# Tips for golfing in PowerShell

Tags: code-golf, tips, powershell

What general tips do you have for golfing in Windows PowerShell? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to PowerShell (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

—taken nearly verbatim from [marcog's question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Comment: When I googled "PowerShell golf" this was the first hit!

Answer (score 28):

Powers of 10 literals with scientific notation:

```
4e6 = 4000000
```

Powers of 2 literals:

```
4KB = 4096
4MB = 4194304
4GB = 4294967296

# TB and PB suffixes also exist, but less useful for golf.
```

Could come in handy.

Answer (score 24):

If you need to run a loop, and you know *exactly* how many times it needs to run every time, consider piping an array of contiguous integers into `ForEach-Object` via the `%` alias instead of using `for`.

`for($x=1;$x-le10;$x++){`...`}`

vs

`1..10|%{`...`}`

Answer (score 20):

You can skip spaces *a lot* in PowerShell. If it feels like it might not be needed, it quite possibly isn't. This is particularly useful in comparisons.

Example:

```
$x-eq$i-and$x-ne9
```

vs.

```
$x -eq $i -and $x -ne 9
```

---

If you need to branch your script based on the result of a single test which may have multiple outcomes, `switch` can sometimes match or beat an if statement.

Example (switch vs. if/else - tie):

```
if($x%2-eq0){'even'}else{'odd'}
```

vs.

```
switch($x%2){0{'even'}1{'odd'}}
```

Or (switch vs. if/elseif/else - switch wins by 15):

```
if($x%2-eq0){'even'}elseif($x%2-eq1){'odd'}else{'error'}
```

vs.

```
switch($x%2){0{'even'}1{'odd'}2{'error'}}
```

If the switch is *actually* based on certain math results, like the modulo operation above, you can replace the switch entirely with an array. Here, it saves another 13 characters and is even shorter than the original two-option if/else statement. (Thanks to [Danko Durbic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12177/collatz-conjecture/15220?noredirect=1#comment29076_15220) for this bit.)

```
('even','odd','error')[$x%2]
```

If you will be using a particular command a lot, especially one without a pre-existing short-hand alias, set up a single-character alias early on.

Example:

```
nal g Get-Random;g 10;g 10;g 10
```

vs.

```
Get-Random 10;Get-Random 10;Get-Random 10
```

Comment: `('even','odd')[$x%2]` FYI.

Answer (score 16):

Encapsulating the command that defines a variable in parenthesis allows you to feed the variable's definition directly to other commands.

For example, you can set $x and then set $y based on the value of $x in one shot with this:

```
$y=($x=1)+1
```

Instead of this:

```
$x=1;$y=$x+1
```

You can set $h and output it with this:

```
($h='Hello World!')
```

Instead of this:

```
$h='Hello World!';$h
```

Comment: This is especially useful for calling methods on objects. `($x=New-Object Windows.Forms.Form).Controls.Add($t)`

Answer (score 15):

A switch can act like a loop, when given an array. For example:

```
$FooBarMeh='a','b','c'
switch ($FooBarMeh)
{
    'a'{'FOO'}
    'b'{'BAR'}
    default{'MEH'}
}
```

Will output:

> FOO
>   BAR
>   MEH

I'm not totally sure where this will be useful, but I expect it will be handy for someone some time.

Comment: It is handy every time you need a `ForEach-Object` and a `switch` within that. It's for example (in real-world) code very nice for writing quick parsers of text files where you need to do different things depending on which regex a line matches.

Comment: This is... damn weird. An array shouldn't match with a char, but it does.

Comment: @Joey That's what `switch -File $path` is for

Comment: Not everything that's parsed happens to be a file.

Answer (score 13):

Want to find the maximum or minimum of a collection of values? Tried

```
(...|measure -ma).Maximum
```

or

```
(...|measure -mi).Minimum
```

already?

Just sort and use the last or first item:

```
(...|sort)[-1]  # maximum
(...|sort)[0]   # minimum
```

Comment: And, if you know the length of the collection of values and it's less than 10...

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Oh, maximum lengths can often be employed creatively, not necessarily being 10. Although for this particular case I don't recall an instance where it ever helped.

Comment: I mean, if the final item is known to be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` or `9`, it would save a byte to write the known length instead of `-1`.

Answer (score 13):

Replace `[math]::pow` with multiplication. Instead of

```
[math]::pow($a,$b)
```

you can write

```
"$a*"*$b+1|iex
```

This works for integer exponents >= 0.

Comment: I needed to see [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/779/85024) to understand `iex` ... Alias for `Invoke-Expression`

Answer (score 13):

## Shortening Property Names

Sadly, unlike parameters, properties/methods (anything accessed with a dot `.`) cannot usually be shortened down to its unambiguous form.

But certain cmdlets can operate on property names and take wildcards, and there are little-known parameter sets of `%` and `?` that can be useful.

Usually we pass in a scriptblock and refer to the item with `$_`, but there's another form of these that takes a property name, and it accepts a wildcard.

```powershell
$o|select Le*  
$o|%{$_.Length}
```

With a property like `.Length` we can't use the v3 magic that would normally work on an array because `Length` is a property of the array itself, so the above two could be used to get the lengths of the individual members. The `select` comes in a little bit shorter.

But `%` can take a property name directly and return that value:

```powershell
$a|% Length
```

Which can be shortened with wildcards. The wildcard must resolve to a single property (or method, more on that later), so it will throw a helpful error if it doesn't, indicating exactly which members it could resolve to.

In the case of `Length`, `Le*` is typically the shortest. Even on a single string, this method is 1 byte shorter than just using the property.

```powershell
$a.Length                # 9   #(doesn't work on array)
$a|%{$_.Length}          # 15
$a|% Le*                 # 8
```

But depending on what you're doing with this, this can be worse. You can do `$a.Length*5` but to do it with the pipeline expression you'd have to wrap it `($a|% Le*)*5`; might still be worth it if it's against an array, but the point is it's not always appropriate as a straight substitution.

It works with methods too, and you can leave off the `()` which makes a full name the same length, but same restriction as above about sometimes having to wrap it. <s>The method must have an overload that takes no parameters</s> (you can pass arguments by placing them after the method name, which is really nice):

```powershell
$a.ToUpper()             # 12
$a|% *per                #  9
```

With arguments:

```powershell
'gaga'-replace'g','r'    # 21
'gaga'|% *ce g r         # 16
```

These aren't strictly the same in that the `-replace` operator does a regex replace, but if you're just doing a string replace, it can (now) be shorter to use the method; it helps that the strings are cmdlet arguments instead of method arguments so they don't need to be quoted.

### Where-Object Properties

`?` can take (partial) property names as well, and apply an "operator" to it (in the form of switch parameters). Again this can be shorter than using the standard `Where-Object` scriptblock approach if the property name is sufficiently long and unique.

```powershell
$a|?{$_.Length-gt5}      # 19
$a|? Le* -GT 5           # 14

($a|% Le*)-gt5           # 14 - Lengths, not objs
```

Comment: One of the few places where whitespace is required. Nice find, though. I can think of several areas where this will shorten things.

Comment: Nice edit Joey! Thanks.

Comment: Found you a way to get it shorter ;-) ... the sad thing about this is that as a whole it's a pipeline again, which limits its usefulness a bit. Or rather, there are a lot of places where you'd have to wrap it into parentheses again to get an expression. But few golf techniques are without trade-offs ...

Comment: @Joey yeah I mentioned that, it really does depend. If you're passing it along in the pipeline or just returning it it's great, otherwise it may need wrapping; even with wrapping it could be shorter in certain situations.

Comment: Also, one point where this breaks down: The automatic Count property introduced in PSv3 for any object. Doing `''.Count` returns 1, but `''|% Count` returns nothing since there isn't *actually* a Count property there.

Comment: @Joey yeah I did notice that.. but typically in golfing you're going to know when to use `.Count` or not, whether it's an array of single object, in advance, but that's a good thing to know. It could end up being confusing.

Comment: Used this on `.ToString` [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115117/59735) to save a tonne, you can pass params through to methods by placing them after it.

Comment: @ConnorLSW ah yes I meant to update this as I'd since realized you can pass args that way, which greatly ups its usefulness. Great use of `.ToString()`!

Comment: @briantist this has turned PowerShell into a much more competitive language, really cuts out some of the annoyingly verbose .Net calls.

Comment: @ConnorLSW I added an example with parameters too; if you have others please feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 12):

Comparison operators work on collections of values by returning matching values:

```
1..5 -gt 2
```

will yield `3`, `4` and `5`. In some cases this can help to save an otherwise longer `|?{$_...}`.

`-match` is a comparison operator too.

Comment: Note that you don't need spaces in that example `1..5-gt2`

Comment: I know; this was more about showing the technique. Spaces are [in a separate answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15270/15).

Answer (score 12):

Use aliases whenever possible. There are a bunch of useful ones:

```
?        Where-Object
%        ForEach-Object
gu       Get-Unique
sort     Sort-Object
iex      Invoke-Expression
```

Answer (score 10):

`for` loops can have anything between 0 and three statements in their header:

Endless loop:

```
for(){}
```

Loop with initialization:

```
for($n=0){}
```

Loop with initialization and end condition:

```
for($n=0;$n-lt7){}
```

In such cases the additional semicolons at the end may be omitted (it's explicitly stated in the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=9706), so it's not an implementation detail) in contrast to C-like languages which always require exactly three statements.

This also makes `while` a bit shorter. Compare

```
while(...){}
```

and

```
for(;...){}
```

With the added bonus that you can stick in a previous line (if there is one) into the `for` as well without extra cost (and even saving a character).

Answer (score 10):

Finding a sum the long way:

```
(...|measure -s).Sum
```

A shorter way:

```
...|%{$s+=$_};$s
```

And even shorter:

```
...-join'+'|iex
```

Answer (score 9):

The `Get` verb is implied. This can shorten any `Get-Frob` to just `Frob`. Frequent contenders are `date` or `random`.

Note that this *won't* work properly in some cases because you might have GNU utilities in your path (or other native programs that clash). Order of command lookup in that case seems to prefer the native program before it considers cmdlets with the `Get-` removed:

```
PS Home:\> date

Freitag, 15. November 2013 07:13:45


PS Home:\> $Env:Path += ';D:\Users\Joey\Apps\GnuWin32\bin'
PS Home:\> date
Fr Nov 15 07:14:13 W. Europe Standard Time 2013
```

Comment: This doesn't *quite* always work out as expected. I have a script that starts with `nal g Get-Random` to save characters later on. Changing it to `nal g Random` causes the script to hang indefinitely (or, at least, take an inordinate amount of time to process - I haven't had the patience to wait for it to end, but it's taking several orders of magnitude longer than the original form before I abort).

Comment: Two short `Measure-Command` invocations (100 times `Get-Random` vs. `random`) tell me it's about 500 times slower. I didn't know that before, to be honest. But it's good to keep it in mind, especially in loops with many iterations. That being said, golfed code should be short, not fast (*that* being said, it sucks to have to wait two days for an answer to a Project Euler problem).

Comment: My problem was running [10,000 iterations of the Monty Hall scenario](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/13008/9387) each requiring three iterations of Get-Random. A 50,000% increase in processing time, multiplied across 30,000 runs is pretty nasty.

Comment: Wow. It looks like the same probably holds true for any alias. Tested `Get-Variable` vs. `gv` and got a similar comparison.

Comment: I suspect it is because of what I added in the answer this morning – the implied `Get-` seems to be after everything else in the command lookup list, which means everything on the `PATH` needs to be checked first. I cannot look into the implementation though, lest I want to be unable to continue working on Pash.

Comment: That could be it. I did some math and figured my Monty Hall script should take about 1.5 hours (normally, 10-11 seconds) to run without `Get-`. That's a pretty gnarly bloat in run time for a savings of just 4 characters in length.

Comment: Another interesting bit: An alias e.g.: `nal g random` seems to not be functional in PS 2.0. The alias gets created, but it's unresolvable when you try to use it - even though `random` works. The alias worked fine (minus the lag) in 4.0.

Answer (score 9):

Semicolons and line breaks are interchangeable. Golfed code is often more readable if not jammed into a single line. And the length is still the same (provided you use U+000A as line break which PowerShell handles without problems).

Comment: Wait, we are worried about readability?!

Comment: If it has no effect on the length ... why not?

Comment: Doesn't it technically make a difference since a semicolon is one less character than \r\n? Only in Unix it is a singular \n.

Comment: @Vasili: You can save the files just fine with only U+000A between the lines. PowerShell won't complain. Which I wrote in the answer already, by the way. Line breaks are a property of the *file*, not of the operating system it is used on. No one says that you cannot use Unix line endings on Windows.

Comment: @Joey If you’ve used a fresh install of windows to do some quick programming, you’ll notice that Notepad doesn’t play nice with \x0a

Comment: @StanStrum: So? Don't use Notepad, then, or wait for the next update of Windows 10 where Notepad *will* handle Unix line endings. If it bothers you too much, you can still use semicolons just fine. Besides, these days PowerShell also runs on other operating systems than Windows by now.

Comment: @Joey I didn’t mean it that way.  I was just expressing how annoying `\r` is... it’s so archaic, too much so to be used pedantically imo

Comment: All major operating systems have archaic remnants embedded into their design ;)

Answer (score 8):

Casting to string:

```
[string]$x
```

vs.

```
"$x"
```

Casting to string like this can also be used to flatten an array of strings, instead of joining it:

```
$a = @('a','b','c')
$a -join ' '
```

vs.

```
$a = @('a','b','c')
"$a"
```

Casting a string to a numeric type:

```
[int]$x     [float]$x
```

vs.

```
+$x
```

Also very useful to know that PowerShell *always* takes the type of the left operand to determine the final type of an expression and conversions to apply:

```
'1'+2    -> '12'
1+'2'    -> 3
```

which can help determining where needless casts are.

Answer (score 8):

If you are assigning an array that you know will only have two values, don't use indexing.

Something like this:

```
$a="apple","orange"
$a[0] # apple
$a[1] # orange
```

Can easily be turned into this:

```
$a,$o="apple","orange"
$a # apple
$o # orange
```

This can also be useful for if you just need to the first element of an array:

```
$a,$b=1..10
$a # 1
$b # 2..10
```

Comment: In this case (with the strings) `$a="apple";$o="orange"` is identical in length. It's the longer arrays that can sometimes be optimised fairly nicely, e.g. by putting all elements in a string with a separator and then using `-split` (best to use whitespace as separator because then the unary `-split` will suffice).

Answer (score 6):

When using a number as an argument to an operator that would otherwise require a string, you can use the number directly. Compare

```
...-join'0'
```

vs.

```
...-join0
```

Works with `-split` as well. The argument is always converted to a string first.

Comment: For reference, this works with `-replace` as well.

Comment: `-replace` also works with no second argument wheb you want to remove matches,

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget that you don't always need to provide the full name of a parameter, and some parameters are positional.

```
Get-Random -InputObject (0..10)
```

...can be trimmed to...

```
Get-Random -I (0..10)
```

...because "I", in this case, is enough to uniquely identify `InputObject` from the other valid parameters for this command.

You could trim it further to...

```
Get-Random (0..10)
```

...because `InputObject` is a positional parameter.

Piping is usually shorter than feeding objects as a parameter, especially when it can remove the need for parenthesis. Let's trim our random number generator further...

```
0..10|Get-Random
```

Also be on the lookout for other ways to accomplish the same thing, even if you can't change the command. For the above case, you could do this:

```
Get-Random 11
```

Or, incorporating [another suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/778/9387)*:

```
Random 11
```

**Note: Omitting `Get-` from a command name can bloat the run time by about 50,000%. Not bad if you only need the command once, but be careful using it in long loops.*

And that's how can knock a simple command down to a third of its size.

Answer (score 6):

Automatic variables have booleans for True and False as `$true` and `$false` but you can get similar results using the logical not operator `!` and the integers 0 and 1( or any non-zero integer.)

```
PS C:\Users\matt> !1
False

PS C:\Users\matt> !0
True
```

Near all PowerShell expressions can be evaluated as booleans. So as long as you are aware of how certain data is evaluated you can get booleans and never need to explicitly cast them. Be aware of the LHS value when doing these.

- Integer 0 is false and non-zero integers are evaluated to true.
- non-zero length strings are true and empty or null (and nulls themselves) strings are false.

There are other examples but you can easily test by doing a cast

```
PS C:\Users\matt> [bool]@(0)
False
```

Comment: Many other data types also have similar status. Uninitialized variables default to `$null`, which is falsey. The empty string (and variables set to the empty string) are falsey. Etc. This can then be used to shortcut indexing into an array (e.g., when doing an `if`/`else`), as was used in [FizzBuzz](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58624/42963).

Comment: @TimmyD Very true. Using `int`s is just shorter

Comment: @TimmyD I wanted to answer fizzbuzz until I saw yours.... Can't beat that .... at least not yet

Comment: Note that in many cases you don't actually _need_ a `bool`. You can use `0` and `1` just as well. Implicit conversions help a lot in that regard (which you can often force with certain operators).

Answer (score 6):

Fake ternary operator. You can assign straight from an `if` statement:

```
$z=if($x-eq$y){"truth"}else{"false"}
```

But you can use a 2-element array and use the test to index into it. $falsey results get element 0, $truthy results take element 1:

```
$z=("false","true")[$x-eq$y]
```

NB. that this is really doing array indexing, and if the test results in a value which *can* be cast to an integer, you'll ask for an item outside the bounds of the array and get $null back, and will need to do `!(test)` to force cast the result to a bool, with the options reversed.

[ Edit: There's a genuine ternary operator in PowerShell 7+ in the C-language-style `cond ? 1 : 0` ]

Comment: The first snippet didn't work at one point in time (older PowerShell versions), if I remember correctly, making it necessary to wrap it into `$()`. There was essentially a distinction of using pipelines made from commands and statements as expressions. Seems that is gone by now, at least in PowerShell 5.

Comment: Additionally, if the array elements are non-static, *both* get parsed and processed as part of the array creation before the indexing happens and the result is assigned. [For example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74652/42963).

Answer (score 5):

Absolute value

With

```
$n=-123
```

Instead of

```
[math]::abs($n)
```

use

```
$n-replace'-'
```

Of course, the savings are cancelled if parentheses are needed.

Comment: Or if you need the result on the left side of an operator ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you need to silence errors, the obvious variant would be

```
try{ <# something that throws errors #> }catch{}
```

However, this is way too long. A shorter variant is to run the `try` block as a script block and just redirect the errors into an unset variable (`$null` would be the usual one, but that's still too long):

```
.{ <# something that throws errors #> }2>$x
```

This saves five valuable bytes (if not the world).

Answer (score 5):

Use the `$ofs` [special variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) to change the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator used when stringifying an array. Useful if you're needing to transform arrays to strings multiple times.

For example:

```
$a=1,2,3,4
$a-join',';$a-join','
$ofs=',';"$a";"$a"
```

Saves 2+*n* characters on the 2nd `-join`, where *n* is the length of the separator, and saves an additional 5+*n* for the 3rd `-join` and each thereafter.

Comment: Sadly very rarely useful (at least in my golfing so far – I tend to strip it down to only a single join at the end).

Answer (score 5):

### **Use `[bigint]` instead of `[Math]::floor`**

The `bigint` datatype is a numeric type that can store arbitrarily large numbers and holds no decimal values. It always floors when using `[bigint]::new()`.

A suffix for it was added in PowerShell core but using the `n` prefix rounds normally instead of floor which doesn't work for this.

Example:

```
[bigint](.9)        # 0
[bigint]3/4         # 0
[bigint](.1)        # 0
[bigint]1/4         # 0
[bigint]10.5        # 10
[bigint]100/3       # 33

(.9)n               # 1
3/4n                # 1
(.1)n               # 0
1/4n                # 0
10.5n               # 11
100/3n              # 33
```

Comment: only from PS7+. does not work with TIO yet. because TIO use PS6. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7

Comment: @mazzy ps5 works for the first method

Comment: yes, it is. `$x-$x%1` is better [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XC1tBA35hLpUJXpULVkCs6KTM9M68kVqWCKxpKc6lU2hrrmwApXZVKZCWVUCWV//8DAA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Comment: @mazzy that saves bytes when you have defined variables, if you are doing a one-time computation you don't need variables and it saves 3 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

`Invoke-Expression` and `Get-Random` can also get pipeline input instead of arguments.

For `iex` this allows to save parentheses on some expressions:

```
iex 1..5-join'+'   # won't work
iex(1..5-join'+')  # does work, but has extra parentheses
1..5-join'+'|iex   # doesn't need the parentheses
```

In case of `random` this allows a common case to be optimized a bit:

```
random -mi 10 31   # gets a random integer between 10 and 30
10..30|random      # much better :-)
(random 21)+10     # if needed in another expression that doesn't require extra
                   # parentheses
```

The latter way of using it simply selects an item from a list. The `-c` argument can be given to allow more than a single selection.

Answer (score 4):

Consider storing repeated script blocks in variables, instead of using functions.

I was going to use this to save some characters in [my Rock, Paper, Scissors implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15386/9387) before I realized that re-writing the function as a variable made even the variable unnecessary. This could still be useful for other scripts though, where you're actually running the same code multiple times.

```
function Hi{echo 'Hello, World!'};Hi
```

vs.

```
$Hi={echo 'Hello, World!'};&$Hi
```

Comment: Useful for functions that do not take arguments. Otherwise the `params(...)` would take up more space than the function definition saves. Related: Use `filter` over `function` when you can do so.

Comment: You could use `$args` to avoid the need for `params`; i.e. `$x={$args[0]+2}` (or even `$x={2+"$args"}`); may save a character or 2 in some circumstances.  You can also combine this with another trick for multiple params: `$x={$a,$b=$args;$a+$b+3}`

Answer (score 4):

Converting floating-point numbers to integers in PowerShell is a bit of a minefield. By default the conversion does [Bankers Rounding](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BankersRounding) which doesn't always trim off the decimal and leave the smaller whole number, or always round .5 up to the next number like people do casually, it rounds evens one way and odds another way - this can be surprising, e.g.

```
PS C:\> [int]1.5
2

PS C:\> [int]2.5
2
```

and break codegolf calculations. Many other common languages do truncation-rounding, therefore golf questions often require truncation. You might reach for `[Math]::Floor()` as the next best thing, but beware this only behaves the same as truncation for positive numbers, but it takes negative numbers lower - further away from zero. `[Math]::Truncate()` is what you need to bring PS behaviour in line with other language's default rounding, but it's a lot of characters.

Regex replacing digits after the decimal point can help save a couple of characters:

```
[Math]::Truncate(1.5)
[Math]::Floor(1.5)
1.5-replace'\..*'

[Math]::Truncate($a)
[Math]::Floor($a)
$a-replace'\..*'
$a.split('.')[0]        # literal character split, not regex pattern split
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Use variables to store .NET names

As outlined by cogumel0 in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148058/42963), you can use variables to store .NET type names. For example, changing

```
param($a)$a-[math]::pow(2,[math]::floor([math]::log($a,2)))
```

into

```
param($a)$a-($m=[math])::pow(2,$m::floor($m::log($a,2)))
```

saved 3 bytes in this example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$s|% t*y` instead `[char[]]$s` to split a string to char array.
Given from [TessellatingHeckler's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158441/80745): `% t*y` expands to `| ForEach-Object -Method ToCharArray` equiv. of `"$args".ToCharArray()`

For example, compare

```
$s|% t*y
```

and

```
[char[]]$s
```

and

```
$s.ToCharArray()
```

It's useful with `$args` especially: `$args|% t*y`

Comment: That's quite neat. I've used the `%` trick for members a few times as well, but most of my golfing predates that feature ;-). It's quite a general technique as well: Try finding a letter/wildcard combination that matches the property/method you need (and is shorter than the real thing).

Comment: Another useful examples from the answer: `$s|% *per` for `$s.toUpper()` and `$s|% *wer` for `$s.toLower()`. I'm agree that's quite neat.

Comment: [One more example](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115117/80745): `|% t* "ddd\:hh\:mm\:ss"` for `[TimeSpan].toString("ddd\:hh\:mm\:ss")`

Comment: Well, that's just a waste of quotes, then; you don't need them here :-)

Comment: ok. the quote formatted as regular text. please feel free to make any changes

Comment: [In addition to that submission I wrote an entire outline of this feature right here in this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/30402) :)

Answer (score 4):

You can access static methods via instance:

```ps
$x=4,2,3
$x::Sort($x) # [Array]::Sort($x)
"$x" # 2 3 4
$x::Reverse($x) # [Array]::Reverse($x)
"$x" # 4 3 2
```

BigInteger suffix (`n`) introduced in PowerShell 7:

```ps
(0n)::Pow(4,5) # [bigint]::Pow(4,5)
(0n)::Abs(-3) # [bigint]::Abs(-3)
2*0n::Abs(-3) # some cases don't require parentheses
```

Comment: Thanks. `n` suffix [introduced in PS7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.1). So you should notice about it. `$x::Reverse($x)` does not work for me

Comment: @mazzy It works on [TIO](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X6XC1kTHSMeYS6XCyio4v6hEQ6VCU0FZIdqxqCixMhYhxqWkUqEEVhWUWgbUnoquEEkYrPb/fwA)

Comment: TIO is highly customized enironment. moreover, powershell for windows is different from powershell for linux (see `sort` alias). Please check your advises with local environment.

Comment: It works in all environments that i have: 7.1.1 Core (Windows), 5.1 (Windows), [code.golf](https://code.golf/fizz-buzz#powershell) (7.1.2 Core (Linux)).

Comment: Oh, that's convenient and news to me. Nice.

Comment: For some reason inexplicable to me, `,0n::Pow(2,64)` also works.

Answer (score 3):

#### Use Boolean logic in place of if-counters in a loop

Suppose you're adding all even numbers from 1 to 10 ... `2+4+6+8+10=30`

```
1..10|%{if($_%2-eq0){$o+=$_}};$o
```

You could use Boolean negation to shorten it to

```
1..10|%{if(!($_%2)){$o+=$_}};$o
```

to save a byte, but how about instead use implicit casting of Booleans to ints, and roll the conditional into the accumulator

```
1..10|%{$o+=$_*!($_%2)};$o
```

Saves 6 bytes in this example.

Comment: Jesus christ. I'm planning to do this in my production code at work, my colleagues will love me for it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Reversing an array

Comes in handy in a lot of [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) challenges where the output is mirrored in some fashion.

Suppose you have

```
$a=1,2,3,4,5
```

The traditional reversal method is long, boring, and doesn't leave the array on the pipeline for immediate use.

```
[array]::reverse($a)
```

Indexing directly into the array in reverse order saves a few bytes, since it leaves the results on the pipeline, but is still rather long:

```
$a[($a.count-1)..0]
```

Instead, try a loop

```
$a|%{$a[-++$i]}
```

Comment: the reverse indexing works well when there's an upper bound for the count

Answer (score 3):

Starting with PowerShell Core 6, you can also use ranges for characters:

```
'a'..'z'
```

which can replace the much more cumbersome

```
0..25|%{[char]($_+97)}
```

Comment: Oh, this is going to come in so handy.

Comment: `[char[]](65..90)` is also a handy way to generate the alphabet

Answer (score 3):

A simple one but control-flow statements (as opposed to pipelines), such as `if`, `for`, and `while`, do not need a semi-colon after their braces.

E.g.

```
# Control-flow statements (All are valid)
if(...){...}"foo"
for(...){...}"foo"
while(...){...}"foo"
switch(...){...}"foo"

# Pipelines
1..2|%{...}"bar" #This will throw an error.
1..2|%{...};"bar" #This will work.
```

A free byte that's easy to miss.

Comment: Good point. I've been using this for ages. I've also taken the liberty of using the correct terms in your answer; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Joey S'all good.

Answer (score 3):

## `SLS` instead `-match`

You can use an `sls` cmdlet (alias for [Select-String](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String)) with `|% M*` as [shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) for property `Matches` instead a `-match` operator with a `$Matches` automatic variable. Compare:

`$args|sls 'pattern'|% M*`

vs.

`if("$args"-match'pattern'){$Matches}`

---

You can also use `sls` with `-a` parameter (`-AllMatches`) to find all matches:

`$args|sls 'pattern'-a|% M*`

---

Also, you can find all matched lines in a multiline string without explicitly line breaking. It need to use a [regexp option](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#regular-expression-options) `?(m)`. Compare:

`$args|sls '(?m)^pattern$'-a|% M*`

vs.

``` $args-split"``n"|%{$_-match'^pattern$';$Matches} ```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `[bool]` for boolean conversion you can instead use `!!`

```
1         # 1
[bool]1   # True
!!1       # True

0         # 0
[bool]0   # False
!!0       # False
!!$null   # False
```

Comment: use [int] as is. the `!!` is redundant for [int]. use `!` and `!!` for [object] to [bool] conversation. [string] -is [object] :)

Comment: @mazzy This was more meant for in a case where you are golfing something and the result has to be `True` or `False` so the output of `1` would not work, I agree with you though :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you need an `if`/`else` at the end of the program (maybe to handle a special case differently), then instead of

```
if(foo){a}else{b}
```

do

```
if(foo){a;exit}b
```

which saves a character.

Answer (score 2):

Declaring an anonymous function should come up alot. There are multiple variations of this that are covered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995667/lambda-expression-in-powershell involving scripts blocks. I use a similar one to this

```ps
$a={iex([int[]][char[]]$args[0]-join"+")}
&$a 'abcd'
```

This would save a few character from declaring a function with a name and goes better if used more than once. The one above converts a string into a char array then into an int array. Then creates a string joined with + so that Invoke-Expression will add all the values.

Comment: I realize now that this is similar to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15432/52023 but this one shows use with arguments and input.

Answer (score 2):

When declaring a hard-coded list of strings, depending on the size of the strings and the number of them, it's often shorter to split a single string up by spaces, since space-delimited splitting doesn't require a delimiter provided as a parameter

For example,

Instead of

```
$numbers='one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten'
```

Do

```
$numbers=-split'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten'
```

You can further delimit with another character and split twice to hold shortened hard-coded multidimensional arrays

Comment: `$numbers=echo one two three four five six seven eight nine ten` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Use `$x-shr$k` if you want to get the result of \$ \big\lfloor{x\over2^k}\big\rfloor \$.

The biggest application of this is getting the truncated int result of halving a positive number without having to deal with Banker's rounding.

Works on ints and floats, however it will cast floats to ints before shifting, resulting in the same banker problem as before. Whether or not this is acceptable will obviously depend. Below is a sample script that shows the results of `-5..10`. `3/2` and `7/2` demonstrate the difference in return value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X9dUT8/QoEa1Wik6M68kVkMlPkHfSNNKiYtTSUEhOCMzrURBwVZJW0FJBSilW5xRZKippFeQmJKTmlaiYaIJVuaXX5SbmANTBjMHaAy6UiWu2v//AQ)

<sup>[Inspired by this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/178758/78849)</sup>

Comment: note that this might not be as useful for negative numbers

Answer (score 2):

## Get `Length` of elements of an array

You can write the name immediately after the point to get the value of the property or method.

```
$a=gci
$a.fullName
```

compare to:

```
$a|%{$_.fullName}
```

Both expressions returns array like this:

```
C:\Archive
C:\PerfLogs
C:\Pictures
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Users
C:\Windows
```

There is a property `Length` which is defined for the array itself. So the Powershell expression `$a.Length` returns the number of elements in an array. You can use the [Shortening Names](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) to get length of elements:

```powershell
$s=@('22','55555','7777777')
$s|% Length       # 11 bytes
```

or shortcut:

```powershell
$s|% Le*          # 8 bytes.
```

Compare to:

```powershell
$s|%{$_.Length}   # 15 bytes
```

Result is the array `2,5,7`, not the number `3`.

Answer (score 2):

## Use the `new()` method instead of `New-Object`

For example, instead of doing the following (37 bytes):

```
New-Object Drawing.Bitmap(1024,1024)
```

Try (32 bytes):

```
[Drawing.Bitmap]::new(1024,1024)
```

Kind of an edge case, but you can do this pretty much anytime you initialize a new .NET object. Sadly, there's no equivalent for COM objects so you still have to use `New-Object` for those :P

Answer (score 2):

String multiplication:

```
"#"*5 ==> #####
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling a command with a string argument, you don't need quotes unless there are spaces:

```
gci MyPath
gci 'My Path'
```

But that space cost you 2 extra bytes. You can save a single byte by escaping the space without quotes:

```
gci My` Path
```

This is only worth it when there's a single space, because there's no advantage with 2 or more.

Answer (score 1):

If a path contains more than 1 space, you can do :

```
gci C:\My*Example*Path
```

instead of

```
gci 'C:\My Example Path'
```

or

```
gci C:\My` Example` Path
```

Comment: Useful to know, although it risks picking up a different but similar path. And I'm not sure how many code golf challenges involve the file system, as I'd be very wary of testing any solution that might be clobbering my system. If you wrote this answer as a continuation of [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166009/15), the `gci` was only for illustrative purposes of a command that may receive an argument with spaces. Not an actual file system golfing trick.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Uppercase over lowercase when dealing with ASCII values

When given the choice, it's usually better to deal entirely with Uppercase. This is because their range is 65..90 vs lowercase's 97..122. For example, the one-liner to generate `ABCD...Z` in PS v5

```
-join([char[]](65..90))
-join([char[]](97..122))
```

This still applies when normalizing mix-case because using the `|%` short-property trick, ToUpper and ToLower shorten to `*per` and `*wer`, respectively.

```
"Lower to upper: "+-join([char[]](97..122))|% *per
"Upper to lower: "+-join([char[]](65..90))|% *wer
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XzcrPzNPIzo5I7EoOjZWw8xUT8/SQFOTC03c0lxPz9DICCjBpeQD0q5Qkq9QWlCQWmSloKSNS3GNqoIWUAmXUihIJUhLDkgvFi0we0E6gCr@//8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Short way to convert bits to integer:

if you trust that `$args` contains `int` only (see Joey's comments below):

```
$args|%{$r+=$_+$r};$r
```

if you assume that `$args` is an array of `int` or `string` representation:

```
$args|%{$r+=+$r+$_};$r
```

`$args` is an array of `char` 48, 49:

```
$args|%{$r+=+$r+"$_"};$r
```

A sliding byte containing 8 bits from the array of `int`:

```
$args|%{($r=2*$r%256+$_)}
```

Compare to:

```
[Convert]::ToInt64($args,2)
```

Comment: Any reason why you're using `$r+=+$r+$_` instead of just `$r+=$_+$r`? Coercion should work the same for the `$null` case.

Comment: Good point. The `+$r` guarantees that `$r` will be converted `$r` to an integer. because  the `array of int` was specified as an incoming condition, you are right: it should be `$args|%{$r+=$r+$_};$r`. Thanks

Comment: That's why I proposed `$_+$r`, as `$_` is already numeric and arithmetic operators convert the right operand to the type of the left. If `$r` were a string `$r+$_` would not do the same as `+$r+$_`.

Comment: `$args` is input parameters. I'm afraid to trust the input parameters so much :) Text fixed. Joey, freely edit the text as you wish. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're tackling a drawing/rendering problem that involves creating, manipulating, and then printing a 2D array, I've found it shorter character-wise to instead deal with a 1D array that you access with `$arr[$y*$width+$x]` rather than `$arr[$y][$x]`.

It's very simple and short to set up the array with blanks or zeroes with something like

```
$arr=@(" ")*$width*$height
```

Half the reason for using 1D arrays is that initialization is much shorter.

To easily print the 1D array as a "2D" array to console, you can use a width-based regular expression to split your array into rows. This will join your array into a string, and then split the string into equally sized chunks and print them in order, effectively printing your 1D array as a 2D array:

```
-join$arr-split"(.{$width})"|?{$_}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Utilize subtraction and booleans in comparisons

If you are in need of an operation like `-ne` and `-gt` and you are counting down, you can use the subtraction operator, `-`, instead of using an extra two bytes

Example:

```
for($i=40;$i-10;$i--){$i}                                         # 40...11
for($i=40;$i-gt10;$i--){$i}                                       # 40...11
for($i=40;$i-ne10;$i--){$i}                                       # 40...11
"$(for($i=40;$i-10;$i--){$i})"`
-eq"$(for($i=40;$i-gt10;$i--){$i})"`
-eq"$(for($i=40;$i-ne10;$i--){$i})"                               # true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fake ternary operator for recursive invocations

If the [fake ternary operator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79895/97729) returns a code block and a function, it can be used to perform recursive invocations:

```powershell
$f={&($f,{result})[condition]}
```

Notice the `{}` around the result and the `&` before the array instead of before the function variable `$f`

Example, a recursive function that returns only when `$r` has the value 1:

```powershell
$f={if($r=(Get-Random)%2){$r}else{&$f}} # with an if else
$f={&($f,{$r})[($r=(Get-Random)%2)]}    # with a fake ternary operator recursive invocations
```