# Print a Christmas Tree

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

**The Challenge**

Print a nice Christmas tree with it's own star at the top using the shortest code possible. The tree star is an asterisk (`*`) and the tree body is made out of `0` The tree must be 10 rows high. Every row should be properly indented in the way that the previous row are centered over the next one. Any given row must have 2 more 0s than the previous, except for the first one that is the star and the second, which has only one 0. The result is something like this:

```
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
```

**Tie break** for resizable height trees without software changes (except changing height parameter)

Please, paste the resulting tree of your code too!

---

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=4114,OVERRIDE_USER=73772;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but there's this one on SO: [Code Golf Christmas Edition: How to print out a Christmas tree of height N](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392788/code-golf-christmas-edition-how-to-print-out-a-christmas-tree-of-height-n)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Golfscript, 27 characters

```
" "9*"*"9,{n\.4$>\.+)"0"*}%
```

The resulting tree looks like this:

```
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
```

A version which uses the height parameter only once is one character longer:

```
9." "*"*"@,{n\.4$>\.+)"0"*}%
```

Reading the height from stdin (with input "10" to generate the example tree) takes the same amount of characters (28):

```
~,)" "*"*"@{n\.4$>\.+)"0"*}%
```

Answer (score 58):

I know this doesn't comply with the spec, but I thought I'd try to add some diversity to the trees here by imitating [this classic ASCII art Christmas scene by Joan G. Stark](https://asciiart.website/joan/www.geocities.com/SoHo/7373/xmas.html#greetings).

I didn't try to reproduce the whole picture — that would've been a bit too much — but just the tree, for which I present this 138-byte Perl program:

```
$_=join$/,qw'11| 8\2_2/ 9(\o/) 5---2/1\2--- 10>*<',map(11-$_.A.AA x$_,2..11),'9\|H|/';s/\d+/$"x$&/eg,s/A/substr">>>@*O<<<",rand 9,1/eg,say
```

And, of course, here's a sample of the output:

```
           |
        \  _  /
         (\o/)
     ---  / \  ---
          >*<
         >O><@
        <><<>><
       @><><>@<<
      @<O><*@*>>O
     OO@@*O<<<*<OO
    ><<>@><<>@<><><
   >><O<>>><@*>>><<O
  *<>*<><<>@><O*>><*<
 O><><<@<*>><O*@>O><>*
O<><<><@O>>*O*OO<><<>O>
         \|H|/
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrdCoIwGADQVxky8qdtn99ASLLR7rqJXmAwDCWMcuaMDHz2VnR1bs7QjrciBGp3V9f1FNjjFSMuZGOklUDKxDhIScE5l4BG/iSYq6yK2b0eEkROrdBCazJTy6QQiCmLS7McFoi3HkyzBhrNdAXthXnQ4J9nP42RUmqfnaqqithY9w0pGf5H/Q7h44apc70P/FiIHPMv)</sup>

The code uses the Perl 5.10+ `say` feature, and so needs to be run with the `-M5.010` (or `-E`) command line switch.  (Actually, just replacing the `say` at the end with `print` would avoid that, at the cost of two more bytes and the loss of the newline after the last line of output.)

Note that the bulk of the tree is randomly generated, so the placement of the ornaments will vary between runs.  The angel, the stand and the top row of the tree are fixed, though.

---

To keep this popular answer from being summarily deleted under [a policy instituted after it was posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990), here's a token spec-compliant solution as well (45 bytes, also Perl 5):

```
$_=$"x10 ."*";say,s/ 0/00/,s/\*?$/0/ while/ /
```

<sup>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lZFqcLQQEFPSUvJujixUqdYX8FA38BAH8iI0bJX0TfQVyjPyMxJ1VfQ////X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA)</sup>

Like the program above, this one also needs to be run on Perl 5.10+ with the `-M5.010` switch to enable the `say` feature.  Obviously (this being a [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) challenge) it produces the exact same boring output as all the other compliant entries, which I won't bother repeating here.  (It's also trivially resizable by changing the number `10` to any other other value.)

Comment: Great! Not by the spec but I think the judges special award is for you! :)

Comment: this kicks the specs' proverbial behind, +2 if I could.

Comment: Sorry, but per the rules, answers that don't meet the spec must be deleted.

Comment: I'm deleting this post in compliance with [our policy about answers not meeting the challenge specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7990/12012).

Comment: Could you please move the valid answer to the top and add a header?

Answer (score 13):

### GolfScript (33 chars)

Fixed-height version:

```
;8:^' '*.'*'+\'0'+^{.(;'00'+}*]n*
```

Or for exactly the same length

```
;8:^' '*.'*'+n@'0'+^{.n\(;'00'+}*
```

The tree looks remarkably similar to everyone else's:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Version which takes height from stdin:

```
~((:^' '*.'*'+\'0'+^{.(;'00'+}*]n*
```

The start of the previous line is one of the better smilies I've made in a "useful" GolfScript program.

Answer (score 10):

## Shell script, 44 characters

```
printf %9c\\n \* 0|sed ':x
p;s/ 0/000/;tx
d'
```

Prints this tree:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Ruby, 46 characters

```
puts" "*8+?*;9.times{|i|puts"%8s0"%(v=?0*i)+v}
```

In order to change the height you would have to change both 8s and of course also the 9.
The output of the program is as follows:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

*Edit*: Inexcusably I omitted the output in the first submission.

Comment: You forgot to post the output. :)

Answer (score 9):

### Maple, 30 / 37 chars

Inspired by [Mr.Wizard's Mathematica entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4139/3191), I present this 30-char Maple 12 command:

```
<`*`,('cat(0$2*i+1)'$i=0..8)>;
```

Output:

```
                              [        *        ]
                              [                 ]
                              [        0        ]
                              [                 ]
                              [       000       ]
                              [                 ]
                              [      00000      ]
                              [                 ]
                              [     0000000     ]
                              [                 ]
                              [    000000000    ]
                              [                 ]
                              [   00000000000   ]
                              [                 ]
                              [  0000000000000  ]
                              [                 ]
                              [ 000000000000000 ]
                              [                 ]
                              [00000000000000000]
```

I can also get rid of the brackets at the cost of seven more chars:

```
`*`;for i in$0..8 do;cat(0$2*i+1);od;
```

Output omitted — it looks just like above, only without the brackets.  Unfortunately, I don't know any way to keep Maple from inserting blank lines between the output rows in text mode.  It looks better in classic worksheet mode.  I guess I could include a screenshot...

[image: screenshot]

(The screenshot shows an earlier 44-char version of the command, but I'm too lazy to retake it.  The output is still the same.)

Oh, and yes, the size is fully adjustable: just replace the 8 with *n*-2 for an *n*-row tree.  With the first solution, going above 25 rows (or 10 in the GUI) requires also setting interface(rtablesize = *n*), though.

(Ps. I thought I'd managed to [beat GolfScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4132/3191) with the latest version, [but alas...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4185/3191))

Answer (score 8):

#### Perl, 42 chars

```
say$"x9,"*";say$"x(9-$_),"00"x$_,0for 0..8
```

Output:

```
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
```

The height of the tree can be changed between 1 and 11 rows by replacing the `8` at the end with values from `-1` to `9`.  Going above 11 rows requires also increasing the two `9`s earlier in the code, which control how far from the left side of the screen the tree is indented.

Comment: This one have 11 rows :P Minor changes I guess

Comment: @Averroes: Yeah, I first assumed it was supposed to be 10 rows _plus_ the star, but then I actually counted the rows in the sample output and fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

## Groovy, 65

```
(p={c,r->println' '*(9-r)+(c*(r*2-1))})'*',1;(1..9).each{p'0',it}
```

Surprisingly, the tree looks like this:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Comment: The 'post the tree output' part is for bringing some Christmas spirit to this site :P

Comment: Also, yours have 11 rows too!

Comment: I can fix that by adjusting the height parameter(s)!

Answer (score 7):

### Python 3: 62 characters

```
print(' '*9+'*',*('\n'+' '*(9-i)+'0'*(i*2+1)for i in range(9)))
```

Output:

```
        * 
        0 
       000 
      00000 
     0000000 
    000000000 
   00000000000 
  0000000000000 
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Note that this essentially beats @Ante's answer by 11 characters, because that answer, when converted to Python 3, uses 73 characters.

Change each `9` to another value for a different height.

Comment: I think you can also lose the space before `for`.

Comment: @badp Thanks—changed from 63 to 62!

Answer (score 7):

## PowerShell, 41

```
" "*8+"*";0..8|%{" "*(8-$_)+"0"+"0"*$_*2}
```

Unsurprisingly, outputs the same tree as everyone else's :-p

If you parametrize that 8, it will yield up to the size of your console, in, say, **48 characters**:

```
" "*($w=8)+"*";0..$w|%{" "*($w-$_)+"0"+"0"*$_*2}
```

Or, as a full-blown script which takes an argument, **53 characters**:

```
param($w)" "*$w+"*";0..$w|%{" "*($w-$_)+"0"+"0"*$_*2}
```

Called, it looks like:

```
PS>: Get-Tree.ps1 8
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 6):

### Python, 59

```
print' '*9+'*'
for i in range(9):print' '*(9-i)+'0'*(i*2+1)
```

Comment: Nice work—this demonstrates that though the answer by @Ante gets longer in Python 3, my Python 3 answer is shorter in Python 2 (`print` not a function).

Answer (score 6):

### Prolog: 183 or 186

```
r(0,_,L,L).
r(N,C,L,[C|T]):-N>0,M is N-1,r(M,C,L,T).
y(S,T,C):-r(T,C,[10],X),r(S,32,X,Y),atom_codes(A,Y),write(A).
x(A,B):-A>0,y(A,B,48),C is A-1,D is B+2,x(C,D).
x(N):-y(N,1,42),x(N,1).
```

Prints:

```
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
false.
```

Could be squeezed further for certain interpreters (e.g. using tab/1 on SWI)

Invoke with x(N).  Where N is the number of rows in the actual tree (excluding star).  Giving it a fixed height would bring it down to 183

Answer (score 6):

**C**

This is Wade Tandy's C version but modified a little bit:

```
           ;
          int
         main(
        ){int i
       =-1,j=0,c
      =10;while(j
     ++<c){printf(
    " ");}{;printf(
   "*");}while(++i<c
  ){for(j=-2;++j<c-i;
 )printf(" ");for(j=0;
++j<2*i;){printf("0");}
          ;;;
        printf(
         "\n")
          ;}}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 50

```
MatrixForm@Prepend[Row/@Table[0,{n,9},{2n-1}],"*"]
```

Answer (score 5):

## PostScript (with parameterised height), 114 characters

```
/h 9 def/b{{( )=print}repeat}def
h -1 0{dup h eq{dup b(*)=}if dup b h sub neg 2 mul 1 add{(0)=print}repeat()=}for
```

Output:

```
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
0000000000000000000
```

What, you wanted it to print out?

Answer (score 5):

## Applesoft BASIC, 143 chars

Since this question reminds me of a homework assignment I had back in high school (when they were teaching on an Apple //e):

```
1INPUTH:X=(H*2)-2:C=(X/2):S$="*":O=0:GOSUB2:S$="0":FORO=0TOX-2STEP2:GOSUB2:NEXT:END
2FORS=0TOC-(O/2):?" ";:NEXT:FORI=0TOO:?S$;:NEXT:?"":RETURN
```

I used the JavaScript Applesoft BASIC found here: http://www.calormen.com/applesoft/

**OUTPUT:**

```
?10
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 5):

### Prolog: 127 characters

```
p:-write('        *'),h(1).
h(L):-(L<10,nl,w(L,-8),h(L+1));!.
w(L,N):-(N<9,N<L,(L>abs(N)->write('0');write(' ')),w(L,N+1));!.
```

Output:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
true
```

Used `Prolog` because I was not able to beat the `Groovy` record without looking at his code :(.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 70 characters

Not so short, but recursive solution :-)

```
def a(s):
 print s
 if s<"0":a(s[1:]+"00")
print" "*8+"*"
a(" "*8+"0")
```

Change 8's to set height.

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 119 characters

Outputs to firebug console

```
i=h=9;a=new Array(h);a[0]=a.join(' ');b=a.join('000');a[0]+='*';while(i)a[i--]=b.substr(i,h+i);console.log(a.join('\n'))


        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Comment: This is 120 characters actually.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 106 characters

7 fewer than the previous:

```
<?php echo str_pad(' ',9)."*\n";for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){echo str_pad("",9-$i).str_pad("",($i*2)+1,"0")."\n";}
```

Comment: enable short tags and save yourself 3 chars, or use the `<?=` and save another 5 from the "echo ".

Comment: I know I'm 8 months late, but http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6783/4967 :)

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (Rhino: 108, Node: 114, Webkit Dev Console: 119, jQuery Plugin: 132)

**Rhino** is the shortest (at 108 characters) because (a) its `print` function has a short name and (b) it'll let you assign built-in functions into a shorter variable name. So:

```
h=10,p=print,m='0',a=Array(h-1),s=a.join(' ');p(s+'*\n'+s+m);while(h-->2){m+='00';a.pop();p(a.join(' ')+m);}
```

**Node.js** comes in a close second (at 114 chars) because its print function `console.log` has a longer name, but it'll let us assign that to a short variable as well:

```
h=10,p=console.log,m='0',a=Array(h-1),s=a.join(' ');p(s+'*\n'+s+m);while(h-->2){m+='00';a.pop();p(a.join(' ')+m);}
```

However, the **Webkit Dev Console** (and probably Firebug, too) thinks `p=console.log` is a bit too sneaky (when you try to call `p()`, it'll complain at you). So, we have to lengthen things out to 119 characters:

```
h=10,m='0',a=Array(h-1),s=a.join(' ');with(console){log(s+'*\n'+s+m);while(h-->2){m+='00';a.pop();log(a.join(' ')+m);}}
```

(Interestingly, `with` only saves us a character).

Finally... a **jQuery plugin** (still tweetable at 132 characters!):

```
$.fn.xms=function(h){var m='0',w=2,l=['*',m];while(w++<h)l.push(m+='00');$(this).css({textAlign:'center'}).html(l.join('\n<br/>'));}
```

And you can invoke it on the footer of this very page: `$('#footer').xms(3)`

Of course, it doesn't have to be a plugin... since we'd probably have to use a JavaScript console to add it to a page and invoke it, we could've just done **a snippet of jQuery**:

```
h=10,m='0',w=2,l=['*',m];while(w++<h)l.push(m+='00');$('#footer').css({textAlign:'center'}).html(l.join('\n<br/>'));
```

which weighs in at a more competitive 116 characters -- in fact, it beats out the other dev console implementation. But, then again, using jQuery and/or the browser's layout engine might be considered cheating. :)

Answer (score 4):

### C, 67

I know this is long over, but it's my first attempt at code golf, and I think I've got a pretty nice C solution.

Interestingly, I came up with this independently of @Patrick's very similar solution.

And yes, I won't win any ties with my hardcoded values ;)  I'm quite pleased, anyway.

```
i;main(){for(;i<10;++i)printf("%*s%0*c\n",i?9-i:8,"",i*2,i?32:42);}
```

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 4):

## LOLCODE, 527 bytes

```
CAN HAS STDIO?
HAI 1.2
IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR VAR TIL BOTH SAEM VAR AN 8
    VISIBLE " "!
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
VISIBLE "*"
I HAS A SPACES
SPACES R 8
I HAS A ZEROS
ZEROS R 1
IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR VAR TIL BOTH SAEM VAR AN 9
    IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR VAR2 TIL BOTH SAEM VAR2 AN SPACES
        VISIBLE " "!
    IM OUTTA YR LOOP
    IM IN YR LOOP UPPIN YR VAR2 TIL BOTH SAEM VAR2 AN ZEROS 
        VISIBLE "0"!
    IM OUTTA YR LOOP
    VISIBLE ""
    SPACES R DIFF OF SPACES AN 1
    ZEROS R SUM OF ZEROS AN 2
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
KTHXBYE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVHBDoIwDL3vK54cPRjhpCczYIRGYIQNIl7VGwn/f8IxGAkhmmgPXdrXvtd2Xd89@udrGCJeIOUKSsckLyzlBP8QMMpBBdoKmZQl6rKcooZX0JQhlDqF4iK3GUNxYjDWkKIwE/Dg7UYKWWvNHQtb0L3HyIpyqJJHQrHpQWV4HHIXlVTMepP3f57obCf63BVs24Kxb54Is61WmhnXa/0nMy22lTl@k1mqPBsuV4spSSATlzD0vi1w11N1PsJTaNBg@zlXnd7CVgzDGw)

### Output:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Comment: This is [tag:code-golf], so please add the byte count of your submission to the header.

Answer (score 4):

#### Oracle

```
select lpad('*', 11) from dual
union all
select rpad(' ', 10 - level) || rpad(' ', level * 2, '0') from dual
connect by level <= 9;


          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 3):

### PHP 113

Figured i'd chime in with a php version:

113 chars (adjust `$h` to change the height, the number of lines includes the star):

```
$h=10;for($n=0;$n<$h;$n++){$i=$n>0?$n:1;$c=$n<1?"*":"0";echo str_repeat(" ",$h-$i).str_repeat($c,($i*2)-1)."\n";}
```

I tried to make it short, not readable and we already knew php can't compete on conciseness so this isn't going to win anything, still a fun little puzzle tho.

output is as spec:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Comment: Hardcoding a litlle bit more, 103 chars, (you can't see the spaces in the first echo inside this comment)

$n=0;echo"        *\n";for($i=9;$i>0;$i--,print str_repeat(' ',$i).str_repeat('0',$n+9-$i)."\n",$n++);

Comment: your hardcoded first line would go out of balance if you change the height of the tree tho :-(

Answer (score 3):

### C, 77

```
i;main(c){printf("%*c\n",c,42);while(i<c)printf("%*s%0*d\n",c-i,"",i++*2+1,0);}
```

Before reading the printf spec more carefully, I had this cute little number down to 138 chars:

```
#define x sprintf(b,
#define y printf(b,
i;main(c){char b[9]="%%%dc\n",*t="%%%ds%%0%dd\n";x b,c);y 42);while(i<c)x t,c-i,i++*2+1),y "",0);}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Java, 192 (198 with param)

`class V{public static void main(String[]a){int c=10,i=-1,j=0;String s="";while(j++<c)s+=" ";s+="*";while(++i<c){for(j=-2;++j<c-i;)s+=" ";for(j=0;++j<2*i;)s+="0";System.out.println(s);s="";}}}`

Prints the requested tree:

```
        *           
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

For variable height, slightly longer:

`class W{public static void main(String[]a){int c=a.length,i=-1,j=0;String s="";while(j++<c)s+=" ";s+="*";while(++i<c){for(j=-2;++j<c-i;)s+=" ";for(j=0;++j<2*i;)s+="0";System.out.println(s);s="";}}}`

Length of command line argument list determines height (e. g. `java W a a a a a` will give height 5).

(This is basically the Java version of Wade Tandy's C solution.)

Comment: I know this was posted a while ago :), but here are two things I see: 1. [you can use an interface instead of a class in java 8](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64713/74635) 2. to save two characters, `while (++i < c) {` -> `for (s += "*";++i < c;s = "") {`, and remove the `s += "*";` and the `s = "";`

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 74 bytes

```
val h=10;println(" "*h+"*");for(i<-0 to h-2)println(" "*(h-i)+"0"*(i*2+1))
```

`h` - height of the tree

Output

```
        *          
        0          
       000         
      00000        
     0000000       
    000000000      
   00000000000     
  0000000000000    
 000000000000000   
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim, 18 bytes

```
17i0<esc>qqYPxr q8@qa*
```

[Try it online](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTdpMBtxcVlQeHIgcThAcWEq&input=) in the backwards-compatible V interpreter!

Although this is a very similar approach as my V answer, this one is *not* non-competing since vim is crazy old. :)

Explanation:

```
17i0<esc>               " Insert 17 '0's
         qq     q       " Start recording into register 'q'
           YP           " Duplicate this line upwards
             x          " Delete one character
              r         " Replace this character with a space
                 8@q    " Playback macro 'q' 8 times
                    a*  " Append an asterisk
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 80

```
i=9,k=10,j;main(F){while(i)putchar(++j<i?32:j<k?48-F*6:(i-=!F,k+=!F,F=j=0,10));}
```

Initialize k to the tree height, i to k-1. F is first line flag. Given no argument, then F should be 1 upon entry.

A slightly longer(81) version where f is non first line flag:

```
i=9,k=10,j,f;main(){while(i)putchar(++j<i?32:j<k?42+f*6:(i-=f,k+=f,f=1,j=0,10));}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lua: 83, 89 or 97

A fixed-height 10-layer tree can be done in 83

```
a=string.rep
for i=0,9 do
print(i<1 and a(" ",8).."*" or a(" ",9-i)..a(0,i+i-1))end
```

Providing a height parameter takes it to 89

```
h=9
a=string.rep
for i=0,h do
print(i<1 and a(" ",h-1).."*" or a(" ",h-i)..a(0,i+i-1))end
```

Changing the first line to `h=io.read()` takes it up to 97, but allows the program to read the height from stdio.

Prints:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Note that the value of `h` is the size of the tree itself, excluding the star.

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 141

```
class t{public static void main(String a[]){char s[]=new char[21];s[9]='*';for(int i=0; i<10;System.out.println(s),s[9+i]=s[9-i]='0',i++);}}
```

Using a char array ..

Answer (score 2):

## Whitespace, 2155 bytes

Program (replace S,T,L with Space,Tab,Linefeed characters respectively):

```
SSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTSTSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTSSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSSSSTTSSSSLTLSSLLL
```

or download the whitespace-only program text-file [christmas_tree.ws](https://sites.google.com/site/res0001/whitespace/programs/christmas_tree.ws).

Output:

```
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
```

This program simply outputs the 164 successive characters that make up the ten rows of the tree (averaging just over 13 program characters per output character). No doubt there's a *much* shorter Whitespace program that uses some logic to generate the blocks of repeated tree characters.

Answer (score 2):

#### T-SQL, <s>151</s> 142 bytes

```sql
declare @ int
set @=10;with t as(select space(@-1)+'*'z,1 i
union all
select space(@-i)+replicate('0',i*2-1),i+1 from t)
select top(@)z from t
```

The height of the tree can be adjusted (just change the value of the `@h` variable)

The query uses a [Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Test link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/1695 (from the "Run SQL" dropdown button, select "Plaintext Output")

If run from the SQL Management Studio select "Results to Text" and use this query, as SSMS displays the data left aligned:

```sql
declare @h int
set @h=10;with t as(select space(@h-1)+'*'as z,1 as i
union all
select space(@h-i)+replicate('0',i*2-1),i+1 from t)
select top(@h)z from t
```

Sample SQL Server Management Studio output:

```sql
z
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
```

EDIT: Saved 9 chars thanks to BradC!

Comment: Nice technique with the recursive CTE. You can save a few bytes by using `@` as the variable instead of `@h`, and by dropping the `AS` column keywords on *z* and *i* (although you'll still need it for table *t*). Also, in SQL 2008 and later you can set the value as part of the declare: `declare @ int=10`

Comment: @BradC Wow, thanks!
I don' t know how I forgot about that `as`, but the `@` var name - I didn't think that was possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 177 Chars

```java
import java.util.Arrays;class C{public static void main(String[]a){
char[]r=new char[17];r[8]='*';int c=10;while(c-->0){if(c<9)Arrays.fill(r,c,17-c,'0');System.out.println(r);}}}
```

*(Line break after `main(...){` only for better readability.)*

Uses API method `Arrays.fill()` to reduce number of while loops.

Prints this tree:

```
        *        
        0        
       000       
      00000      
     0000000     
    000000000    
   00000000000   
  0000000000000  
 000000000000000 
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 230 characters

My own take.

```
class p{public static void main(String[]a){new p().m();}void m(){int h=0;x(20,1,"*");while(h<9)x(20-h,2*h+++1,"0");}void x(int s,int f,String c){for(;s>0;s--)d(" ");while(f-->0)d(c);d("\n");}void d(String s){System.out.print(s);}}
```

And the output:

```
                *
                0
               000
              00000
             0000000
            000000000
           00000000000
          0000000000000
         000000000000000
        00000000000000000
```

The code indented:

```
class p {
public static void main(String[] a) {
    new p().m();
}

void m() {
    int h = 0;
    x(20, 1, "*");
    while (h < 9)
        x(20 - h, 2 * h++ + 1, "0");
}

void x(int s, int f, String c) {
    for (; s > 0; s--)
        d(" ");
    while (f-- > 0)
        d(c);
    d("\n");
}

void d(String s) {
    System.out.print(s);
}
}
```

Adding parameters for height should take only a few more characters, but I am very far way of winning :P

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 83 chars

```
r=replicate
main=mapM_ putStrLn$(r 8' '++"*"):map(\x->r(9-x)' '++r(x*2-1)'0')[1..9]
```

...not as short as I thought it might be.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 147 chars (or 153)

`class V{public static void main(String[]a){int c=10,i=-1,j;while(++i<c){for(j=0;++j<c+i;)System.out.print(j>c+i-2?i<1?"*\n":"\n":j<c-i?" ":"0");}}}`

I based this on Daniel Schneller's solution, although I changed a lot. In line with Daniels solution, this one can be parameterized as well, where the *number* of command line parameters represents the height of the tree:

`class V{public static void main(String[]a){int c=a.length,i=-1,j;while(++i<c){for(j=0;++j<c+i;)System.out.print(j>c+i-2?i<1?"*\n":"\n":j<c-i?" ":"0");}}}`

Output (how surprising :):

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 136 Characters

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

;)

Comment: Now make the size adjustable. :)

Comment: Well, I can't make *this* size adjustable, but I could write [meta-programs](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4178/3269) which can generate PHP programs like these of arbitrary size ;).

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 181 Characters

```
using System;
class T{static void Main(string[]a){
int h=int.Parse(a[0])-2,i=0;
Console.WriteLine("*".PadLeft(h+1));
while(i<=h)
Console.WriteLine(new string('O',i++*2+1).PadLeft(h+i));
}}
```

Output:

```
        *
        O
       OOO
      OOOOO
     OOOOOOO
    OOOOOOOOO
   OOOOOOOOOOO
  OOOOOOOOOOOOO
 OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

Comment: The Main method does not need a string[] input parameter. It can be declared as: static void Main()

Comment: @m0sa It's used to pick up the height from the command line arguments. You can of course make it shorter by hardcoding the height.

Comment: Hmm, looks like my BF answer at least beats something...

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 73 characters

```
main=mapM_ putStrLn$"        *":take 9(iterate((++"00").tail)"        0")
```

And the output:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 64

Yet another python answer.

```
def f(i,c='0'):print' '*(9-i)+c*(i*2+1)
f(0,'*')
map(f,range(9))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 109 characters

```
for($i=10,$j=1,$k=0;$i;$i--,$j+=2,$k=2)echo str_pad(str_repeat($j<2?'*':0,$j-$k),$i+$j-(!$k?1:2),' ',0)."\n";
```

Not the shortest code possible, but easily resizable with changing only the value of $i.

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 167 bytes

```
let r n s=String.replicate n s
let rec x h i=
 let w=r i" "
 match h with|0->w+"*\n"|1->(x(h-1)i)+w+"0\n"|z->(x(h-1)(i+1))+w+(r(z+z-1)"0")+"\n"
printfn "%s"(x 8 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>155</s> 127

```
enum t{_;{for(char c=42,i=9,j;--i<0;c=48){j=i;String b="";while(--j>0)b+=" ";while(++j<(10-i)*2)b+=c;System.out.println(b);}}}
```

and a tree

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 51 bytes

```
puts' '*8+'*';9.times{|a|puts' '*(8-a)+'0'*(a*2+1)}
```

Output:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Comment: Alas, there's already [a shorter Ruby solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4131/3191).

Answer (score 1):

with sed:

```
$ echo $'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'|sed -e '1{ s/^/        */;h;}' -e '2,${x;/ 0/s//000/;/\*/s//0/;h;}'
```

Output:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## VALA, 181

```
void main(string[] argv){int i,h=int.parse(argv[1]);stdout.printf(string.nfill(h-1,' ')+"*\n");for(i=0;i<h;i++)stdout.printf(string.nfill(h-i-1,' ')+string.nfill(2*i+1,'0')+"\n");}
```

The result :

```
[damien@caturday ~]$ ./christmas_tree 5
    *
    0
   000
  00000
 0000000
000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 73 bytes

```
var(h,c)=(10,"*");0+:(0 to h-2)map{i=>println(" "*(h-i)+c*(i*2+1));c="0"}
```

**Output**

```
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. This is a very well golfed answer (+1), however it could benefit from a code breakdown and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 13 bytes

```
17é0òÄlxx>òr*
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=MTfDqTDDssOEbHh4PsOycio&input=)

It's fun to beat the accepted answer by a huge margin. :D

Explanation:

```
17é0            " Insert 17 '0's
    ò     ò     " Recursively:
     Ä          "   Copy this line upwards
      l         "   Move one char to the right
       xx       "   Delete two characters
         >      "   Indent this line
           r*   " Replace the last character with an asterisk
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 38 bytes

```
' '*8+'*'
8..0|%{' '*$_+'0'*(17-2*$_)}
```

Output:

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

## Powershell with parameter, 49 bytes

```
param($h)' '*$h+'*'
$h..0|%{' '*$_+'0'*(17-2*$_)}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **BATCH**, <s>96 90 83 73</s> 71 bytes

Fixed height=10:

```
@set[=          0
@echo%[:0=*%
:0
@echo%[%
@set[=%[:~1%00
@goto:0%[:~1%
```

Saved 6 bytes by replacing `\r\n` line terminators with `\n` (still works)
<s>P.S I'm new to golf, so I'm not sure if `pause` is required.</s> Removed `@pause`, saved 7 bytes.
2020/4/30 - Abused token delimiters `[`, golfed 2 bytes.

[image]

Comment: I would say you do not need `\n@pause`, since it does not change your program's output.

Comment: @JonathanFrech thanks, it's removed

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Tutorial), fixed height: <s>10</s> 8 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
↓*Ｇ↙→→⁹0
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88T0dBSUtJ05orID@nMj0/DyIYlJmeUaKjYOWTmoagLIFKDYBK////r1uWAwA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R22St93uWP2qb@ahtEgg17jT4/x8A).

**Explanation:**

Print the `"*"`, and move the cursor down:

```
Print(:Down, "*");
↓*
```

Draw a polygon in the shape of a triangle, with the initial arm as size 9 and using the character `"0"` as filler:

```
Polygon(:DownRight, :Left, :Left, 9, "0");
Ｇ↙→→⁹0
```

---

**Variable height through input: <s>14</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)**:

```
↓*Ｇ↘←←⊖θ0
```

-5 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88T0dBSUtJ05orID@nMj0/DyIYlJmeUaKjYOWTmoagXFKTi1JzU/NKUlM0CjWB@gyA@v7/NzT9r1uWAwA) or [try it online (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R22St93uWP2qb8ahtAgh1TTu3w@D/f0NTAA).

**Explanation:**

Print the `"*"`, and move the cursor down:

```
Print(:Down, "*");
↓*
```

Draw a polygon in the shape of a triangle, with the initial arm as size `input-1` and using the character `"0"` as filler:

```
Polygon(:DownRight, :Left, :Left, Decremented(q), "0");
Ｇ↘←←⊖θ0
```

Comment: By reversing the order of drawing, you get `↓*Ｇ↙→→⁹0` for 8 bytes.

Comment: @Neil Thanks! And the same golfs 3 bytes in the variable answer, + 2 more because the input can be done implicitly for integers as well now. (This wasn't the case prior, was it? I can remember it wasn't when I posted my first Charcoal answer a few years back.)

Comment: As far as I can remember, I think Decremented has always cast from string to number first.

Comment: I think you forgot to update `Ｇ↗↘←⊖θ0Ｍ⊖θ↑*` to your latest linked code in your explanation?

Comment: @Neil Oops, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org), 27 keystrokes

```
0000<Ctrl-A><Ctrl-D><Ctrl-A><Ctrl-D><Home>0<Ctrl-Shift-R><Ctrl-D><Del><Backsp><Space>
→<Ctrl-Shift-R><Ctrl-Shift-P><Ctrl-Shift-P><Ctrl-Shift-P><Ctrl-Shift-P>
<Ctrl-Shift-P><Ctrl-Shift-P><Ctrl-Shift-P><Ctrl-D><Backsp>*
```

(Newlines included only for readability.)

### Explanation

We'll build the tree from the bottom up:

**The setup**

Starting with four `0`s, we <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (select all, duplicate) twice to get sixteen `0`s. We need seventeen `0`s on the bottom row, so we go <kbd>Home</kbd> and add another one. The cursor is now positioned right after the first `0` on the line.

**The macro**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> starts recording a macro, which we'll use to generate each line from the one below it:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicates the line, leaving the cursor on the upper of the two copies
- Since the cursor is just after the first `0` on the line, <kbd>Del</kbd>  <kbd>Backsp</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> removes two `0`s and prepends a space
- Finally, <kbd>→</kbd> moves one character rightward, so that we are once again right after the first `0` on the line

A second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> ends the macro, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> seven times calls the macro repeatedly to generate the rest of the body of the tree.

**The finishing touch**

For the star, we need only duplicate the top row with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, remove the `0` with <kbd>Backsp</kbd>, and replace it with a `*`.

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 72 bytes

```
say " "*8+"*"
X's0
while 9-X
let Y be 8-X
say " "*Y+0+"0"*X*2
let X be+1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
⁶ẋ8⁾*¶9µ>þa⁶UŒBY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R47aHu7otHjXu0zq0zfLQVrvD@xKBYqFHJzlF/v8PAA)

This is my first time golfing in Jelly; I'm sure this could be golfed further. Advice welcome. :^)

#### Explanation

```
⁶                 Space character
 ẋ8               Repeated 8 times
                  Since this niladic chain doesn't connect to anything, just output it
   ⁾*¶            Two-character string containing * and newline
                  Since this niladic chain doesn't connect to anything, just output it
      9µ          Apply the following monadic chain to a starting value of 9:
        >þ        Make a 9x9 table, where each entry is 1 if the column number is
                  greater than the row number, 0 if not
          a⁶      Logical AND with space (replaces the 1's with spaces)
            U     Reverse each row
             ŒB   Bounce, mirroring each row to the right
               Y  Join with newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
9\*꘍₀(,9n-\0n›*꘍øm
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=9%5C*%EA%98%8D%E2%82%80%28%2C9n-%5C0n%E2%80%BA*%EA%98%8D%C3%B8m&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Fairly well golfed.

```
9                  # 9
 \*                # '*'  
   ꘍               # ' ' * 9 + '*'
    ₀(             # 10 times
      ,            # output
       9n-         # 9 - (iteration number)
          \0       # String '0'
            n›     # iteration number + 1
              *    # That many 0s
               ꘍   # (9 - (iteration number)) spaces + 0s
                øm # Palindromised
```

Tree:

```
         *
         0         
        000        
       00000       
      0000000      
     000000000     
    00000000000    
   0000000000000   
  000000000000000  
 00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
n=-1
exec"print' '*(8-n/2%n),n*'0'or'*';n+=2;"*10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P89W15ArtSI1WamgKDOvRF1BXUvDQjdP30g1T1MnT0vdQD2/SF1L3TpP29bIWknL0OD/fwA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 47 bytes

```python
n=-1
while n<19:print(f"{n*'0'or'*':^19}");n+=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P89W15CrPCMzJ1Uhz8bQ0qqgKDOvRCNNqTpPS91APb9IXUvdKs7QslZJ0zpP29bo/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `C`, 9 bytes

```
17~∷\0*×p
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJDIiwiIiwiMTd+4oi3XFwwKsOXcCIsIiIsIiJd)

```
17~       # the range 1..17 filtered by
   ∷      # is odd
    \0*   # "0" repeated n times for n in those odd nums
       ×p # with an asterisk prepended
          # C flag joins by newlines and centers output
```

Answer (score 0):

### C 145

Takes its heigh param from argc, so set the number of rows by setting the number of arguments:

```
#define x printf
int main(int c){int i=-1,j=0;while(j++<c)x(" ");x("*");while(++i<c){for(j=-2;++j<c-i;)x(" ");for(j=0;++j<2*i;)x("0");x("\n");}}
```

To generate the ten line spec output, you call:

```
christmastree 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Or if you'd prefer to hardcode the height, change `c` in this version:

```
#define x printf
int main(){int i=-1,j=0,c=10;while(j++<c)x(" ");x("*");while(++i<c){for(j=-2;++j<c-i;)x(" ");for(j=0;++j<2*i;)x("0");x("\n");}}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 79 chars

```
s,h=1,10;print " "*(h-s/2)+"*"
for x in range(h):print " "*(h-s/2)+"0"*s;s=s+2
```

```
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
 0000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 68 characters

```
s=sprintf;cat(s('%10s','*'),s('% *s%0*d',9:1,'',1:9*2-1,0),sep='\n')
```

And here's a parameterized version:

```
n=12 # Tree height (without star)
s=sprintf;cat(s('%*s',n+1,'*'),s('% *s%0*d',n:1,'',1:n*2-1,0),sep='\n')
```

Old version, 85 characters

```
cat('         *\n         0\n');cat(sprintf('% *d%0*d',9:2,0,seq(2,16,2),0),sep='\n')
```

I know, not the prettiest - R is not that great at formatting output using compact code.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 89 chars

A fixed-height 10-layer tree can be done in 89 characters:

```
cat(rep("",9),"*\n");for(i in 1:10)cat(rep(" ",10-i),rep("0",seq(1,20,2)[i]),"\n",sep="")
```

Providing a height parameter takes it to 97:

```
h=10;cat(rep("",h-1),"*\n");for (i in 1:h)cat(rep(" ",h-i),rep("0",seq(1,2*h,2)[i]),"\n",sep="")
```

Output:

```
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
0000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

#### PHP-275 Chars

Count is not including any whitespace, resizable by changing function parameter number:

```
function Tenenbaum($n)
{
$r="<br/>";
$x=2;
$v=" ";
$z="0";
$l=str_repeat($v,$n);
echo "$l*$r".$l."0$r";

for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
$s=$n-3;
$p=str_repeat($v,$s);
$q=str_repeat($z,5);
echo str_repeat($v,$n-$i).str_repeat($z,$i+$x).$r;

if($i==$n)
{
echo "$p$q$r$p$q$r$p$q";
}
$x+=1;
}
}

Tenenbaum(20);
```

#### Output:

```
                    *
                    0
                   000
                  00000
                 0000000
                000000000
               00000000000
              0000000000000
             000000000000000
            00000000000000000
           0000000000000000000
          000000000000000000000
         00000000000000000000000
        0000000000000000000000000
       000000000000000000000000000
      00000000000000000000000000000
     0000000000000000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000000000000000
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000
 000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                 00000
                 00000
                 00000
```

Answer (score 0):

## CSV, 133 bytes

Thought I would Cheat Just a little on this one for a few laughs :)

```
        0,
       000,
      00000,
     0000000,
    000000000,
   00000000000,
  0000000000000,
 000000000000000,
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP - 75

```
<?=($p='          ').'*
';for($s=' 0';$p=substr($p,1);$s.='00')echo"$p$s
";
```

For variable heights of 12 or below, modify the hard-coded padding in the above. (Code gets smaller the lower the height)

For variable heights of 13 or more use the following, height param is the second argument to `str_pad`. (Code starts at 77 bytes and doesn't grow as fast as the version with static padding)

```
<?=($p=str_pad('',13)).'*
';for($s=' 0';$p=substr($p,1);$s.='00')echo"$p$s
";
```

Output of `php -d short_open_tag=1 tree.php`

```
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

#### VimScript: 92 characters

I am working at learning Vim and it occurred to me that it could be a neat platform for code golfing. I don't know how to script in Vim that well yet, so any optimization suggestions are appreciated. **Note**: `^[` does not mean a literal caret next to a literal bracket, but is Vim's way of displaying a literal <kbd>ESC</kbd> character in the text.

```
norm8a ^[a*^[9o^[17a0^[ka ^[15a0^[k2a ^[13a0^[k3a ^[11a0^[k4a ^[9a0^[k5a ^[7a0^[k6a ^[5a0^[k7a ^[3a0^[k8a ^[a0
```

Here is the output. One of the unique things about this answer is that the output is created in a buffer in Vim (use a `:new` buffer). The brackets indicate the final cursor location, which ended up where it did for optimization reasons but I think that is cool:

```
        *
       [0]
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

#### Updated: 71 characters

Using mapping to reduce number of characters:

```
map b a0^[k
map c a ^[
norm8ca*^[9o^[17bc15b2c13b3c11b4c9b5c7b6c5b7c3b8ca0
```

#### Updated: 69 characters

Use punctuation instead of letters for the mapped characters in order to save two space characters.

```
map- a0^[k
map. a ^[
norm8.a*^[9o^[17-.15-2.13-3.11-4.9-5.7-6.5-7.3-8.a0
```

#### Updated: 66 characters

Use `nn` ("normal, no remap") for `map` to save 2 letters. Also swap final `a0` for `-`. Note that this results in the cursor resting on the star in the final output rather than on the tip-top of the tree right below the star.

```
nn- a0^[k
nn. a ^[
norm8.a*^[9o^[17-.15-2.13-3.11-4.9-5.7-6.5-7.3-8.-
```

#### Updated: 63 characters

Moving/substituting a few more things allows yet another reduction (ignore the `,` -> `.` change):

```
nn- a0^[O^[
nn, a ^[
norm17-,15-2,13-3,11-4,9-5,7-6,5-7,3-8,-8,a*
```

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp - 100 [nonblank] chars

No Common Lisp solutions? =) Here's mine:

```
(or 
   (format t "~17:@<*~>~%") 
   (format t "~{~17:@<~{0~*~}~>~%~}" 
      (loop for x upto 8 collect 
         (make-list (1+ (* 2 x))))))
```

result:

```
        *        
        0        
       000       
      00000      
     0000000     
    000000000    
   00000000000   
  0000000000000  
 000000000000000 
00000000000000000
```

for higher trees just replace "8" with `(height - 2)` and "17" with `1+2x(height-2)`. Here's a 14 rows tree:

```
CL-USER> (or 
          (format t "~25:@<*~>~%") 
          (format t "~{~25:@<~{0~*~}~>~%~}" 
                  (loop for x upto 12 collect 
                       (make-list (1+ (* 2 x))))))
            *            
            0            
           000           
          00000          
         0000000         
        000000000        
       00000000000       
      0000000000000      
     000000000000000     
    00000000000000000    
   0000000000000000000   
  000000000000000000000  
 00000000000000000000000 
0000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, Fixed height, 136 chars

```c#
class P{static void Main(){for(int i=0;i<10;i++)System.Console.WriteLine((i>0?new string('0',(i-1)*2+1):"*").PadLeft(10+(i>0?i-1:0)));}}
```

Formatted:

```c#
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.Console.WriteLine((i > 0 ? new string('0', (i - 1) * 2 + 1) : "*").PadLeft(10 + (i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0)));
    }
}
```

Output when run:

```c#
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
```

## Variable height: 165 chars

Use commandline parameter to specify height

```c#
class P{static void Main(string[]a){int h=int.Parse(a[0]);for(int i=0;i<h;i++)System.Console.WriteLine((i>0?new string('0',(i-1)*2+1):"*").PadLeft(h+(i>0?i-1:0)));}}
```

Formatted:

```c#
class P
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        int h = int.Parse(a[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
            System.Console.WriteLine((i > 0 ? new string('0', (i - 1) * 2 + 1) : "*").PadLeft(h + (i > 0 ? i - 1 : 0)));
    }
}
```

Output for `foo.exe 15`:

```c#
              *
              0
             000
            00000
           0000000
          000000000
         00000000000
        0000000000000
       000000000000000
      00000000000000000
     0000000000000000000
    000000000000000000000
   00000000000000000000000
  0000000000000000000000000
 000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell

```
tree x=unlines $ (insert 1 '*'):[insert o '0'|o<-[1,3..r]]
    where insert n c=let sur = replicate ((r-n) `div` 2) ' ' in sur++(replicate n c)++sur
          r=2*x+1
```

Here is the output:

```
λ <*Main>: putStr $ tree 10
          *          
          0          
         000         
        00000        
       0000000       
      000000000      
     00000000000     
    0000000000000    
   000000000000000   
  00000000000000000  
 0000000000000000000 
000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>108 bytes</s> 92 bytes

<s>i=9,n=Array(i).join(' '),s='0',a=[n+'*'];while(i--)a.push(n.substr(0,i)+s),s+='00';console.log(a.join('\n'))</s>

edited:

```
i=10,n=' '.repeat(i-1),s='0',t=n+'x';for(;i--;s+='00')t+='\n'+n.substr(0,i)+s;console.log(t)
```

ungolfed:

```
i=10,n=' '.repeat(i-1),s='0',t=n+'x';

for(;i--;s+='00')t+='\n'+n.substr(0,i)+s;

console.log(t);
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! `n='<9 spaces>'` will save you a few bytes over your current setup. You can also save a few bytes by switching to a `for` loop, like so: `for(;i--;s+='00')a.push(n.substr(0,i)+s);` You can also read through the [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/42545) thread for more ways to golf, if you'd like.

Comment: @ETHproductions that's very good tips, thanks

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 71 bytes

```
for(i=z='10';i--;z+='00')console.log('        *'.slice(0,i)+z.slice(3))
```

This challenge seemed to be suffering from a distinct lack of super-short JavaScript answers, so I thought I'd try to make up for that. This is the shortest ES5 solution I have found thus far.

#### Test snippet

```js
for(i=z='10';i--;z+='00')console.log('        *'.slice(0,i)+z.slice(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Brainf*ck, 163 bytes

This could be golfed further, but this is my first serious attempt at golfing in general, so oh well...

```
++++++++++[->+>+>+<<<]>>>++++++[->>++>+++<<<]>>.<<<-[>>>.<<+<-]>>>>------.++++++>+<<<<+.-[-[-<+>>+<]<[->+<]>>>..<[->.<]>>>[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]>[-<<<.>>>]<<++<<<<<<.>>]
```

Output:

```
          *
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## jQuery, <strike>160 152</strike> 143 bytes

Well, I recognize that it's late, and that it didn't beat the other jQuery entries, but it's been a LONG time since I've done any javascript, so here goes:

```
$.fn.x=function(h){for(var i=1,o=" ".repeat(h-2)+"*\n";i++<h;)o+=(i==h?"0".repeat(i+(i-3)):" ".repeat(h-i)+"0".repeat(i+(i-3)))+"\n";return o};
```

Can be run from your browser's javascript console with $().x(10), and accepts any height parameter. Keep in mind, Chrome's console puts a quotation mark at the beginning and end of console output, so that makes the * appear out of place, but it's not.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 113 bytes

```kotlin
{(0..9).map{print(' ')}
println('*')
(0..9).map{(it..9).map{print(' ')}
(0..it-1).map{print("00")}
println('0')}}
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
{
    (0..9).map { print(' ') }
    println('*')
    (0..9).map {
        (it..9).map { print(' ') }
        (0..it-1).map { print("00") }
        println('0')
    }
}
```

### Test

```kotlin
var f:()->Unit =
{(0..9).map{print(' ')}
println('*')
(0..9).map{(it..9).map{print(' ')}
(0..it-1).map{print("00")}
println('0')}}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    f()
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##bcxBCsIwEAXQ/Zxi6CYzQkNcWrTgGcQDZNMSbMcSR0FCzh6jqyz8qw//8W93XYIUePmI00Dcj1cJiqeSyFl7YLv6LW0xiJJBwxl+fREyO8PQGAr6139J0H7fLp1zXXvlKswFpqfg6oOQj/NjwHOM/n28aFXzyJgAayZiyOUD)

Answer (score 0):

## [uBASIC](https://github.com/EtchedPixels/ubasic), 63 bytes

```
0?Tab(9);"*":ForI=0To8:?Tab(9-I);:ForJ=0To2*I:?0;:NextJ:?:NextI
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K01KLM5M/v/fwD4kMUnDUtNaSUvJyi2/yNPWICTfwgoiquupaQ0S9AIJGml5WtkbWFv5pVaUeFnZg2nP//8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [MY-BASIC](https://github.com/paladin-t/my_basic), 95 bytes

```vb
S="         *"
Print S;
For I=0 To 8
Print Left(S,9-I)d
For J=0 To 2*I
Print 0
Next
Print;
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y63UTUoszkz@/z/YVkkBBrSUuAKKMvNKFIKtudzyixQ8bQ0UQvIVLKCiPqlpJRrBOpa6npopYHkviLyRlidUhQGXX2pFCYRjDWb//w8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 71 bytes

```
{for(;$1--;)printf"%"$1-(a==0)"s%0"2*++F-3(a?"d":"s")"\n","",a++?0:"*"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/Oi2/SCPR1s3WwFrFUFfXWrOgKDOvJE1JVQnIBUrYGmgqFasaKBlpaWu76RprJNorpShZKRUraSrF5CnpKCnpJGpr2xtYKWkp1f7/b2jAZWgJAA)

It seems like some simplification should be possible, but I can't find it.

NOTE: The TIO link has a few extra bytes to allow printing multiple trees.

```
        *
        0
       000
      00000
     0000000
    000000000
   00000000000
  0000000000000
 000000000000000
00000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 25 bytes

```apl
' *0'[(⊣⌿⍪+⍨)(⊖,~)∘.≤⍨⍳⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQZcjzra0/6rK2gZqEdrPOpa/Khn/6PeVdqPeldoArnTdOo0H3XM0HvUuQQo8qh3M1Bf7H@glv9pXJZcXGlcRgYA)

```apl
        *         
        0         
       000        
      00000       
     0000000      
    000000000     
   00000000000    
  0000000000000   
 000000000000000  
00000000000000000
```

it's resizable:

```apl
                   *                    
                   0                    
                  000                   
                 00000                  
                0000000                 
               000000000                
              00000000000               
             0000000000000              
            000000000000000             
           00000000000000000            
          0000000000000000000           
         000000000000000000000          
        00000000000000000000000         
       0000000000000000000000000        
      000000000000000000000000000       
     00000000000000000000000000000      
    0000000000000000000000000000000     
   000000000000000000000000000000000    
  00000000000000000000000000000000000   
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000  
000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 165 bytes

I saw some possible changes in the existing Java answer and thought I'd add my answer. (trims off 65 bytes, so I'm pretty proud tbh)

```java
interface p{static void main(String[]a){String s="        ",o=s+"*";for(int i=0;i<9;i++){o+="\n"+s.substring(i);for(int j=0;j<=2*i;j++)o+=0;}System.out.println(o);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcxBDoIwFATQqzRdtVQJcWdKT8ESXVQo5lfpJ/xCYghnr40mzGoWb8bb1Z5xcsH3r5QgRDcPtnNs2ijaCB1bEXo2WgiiiTOEZ3u3cvtXRoazI/yEhhQvuB5wFvmJgak01FcNSskNleG3wBWVtDzotxcgD@uz9bW5FKB95llXem8@FN1Y4hLLKQ/iOwiUet9T@gI)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 69 bytes

```php
while($i<10)printf("%".(8+$i+!$i)."s
",$i++?str_pad(0,$i*2-3,0):'*');
```

Run with `php -nr '<code>'` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a9ea80b14045c1fc01af98cf45511ff39ff2266).

---

Resizable version, 76+1 bytes (run as pipe with `-nR`):

```php
while($i<$argn)printf("%".($argn+$i+!$i)."s
",$i++?str_pad(0,$i*2-3,0):'*');
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 108 bytes

A few years late, but I was searching for something else and it was in my search results. Accepts a input for the rows. Fixing it to 10 rows saves 6 bytes (code below).

```
{n:Int->(0..n).map{if(it<1)" ".repeat(n)+"*"
else " ".repeat(n-it+1)+"0".repeat(it*2-1)}.joinToString("\n")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVXBbuNGDL37KxhfKmUdebzYQ2GkC2wXW6DFAi3QHHsZW5Q1tTSjzozieIN8e/qGIydxNutLIoqP5CMfqb2LnbGPyyV99qwj19Q4T7E1gbauZtq5rqFtq7uO7Y7XMzi2MQ5hvVym9@l1FaLe7vkOXnCptq5f/jdyiMbZsPywWn1IoL@8sZE0fW69CbHXgW488yy9umkZ5inD7KWzNVt@gYhA0MHElkz8KZA7WEJqTzomUESY6AYag7E7eQqt8xGFZCaDC8FsOq4kYYqVUBIAZLUlHSIj1Z6KyxLPdY6Ycm5cfUxOva4F5MZIriH1FIn6EWk2TCtF3h0CtWbXVvTllv0xGSRT68auTk6DdwP7DiFtzTb13FhJdtBH/NUxPSTI4PnWuDGkEKQ90za5ewAcIgvE8h1qsWD1yR4TZmdu2QpAamr1LdN76h3QKqToOdUp9CJhMDse4jR5psb4IEFzMSbkbkqrc1uED2@drRd0aM22RR4MxIJTgqncY89h7BJe3F3PkBVG05k9i8LWMuzn3@X5ozp7VOrsWalzg1KvLEq9Nin1nU2p741KvWFVr39ZuQbawNrspXWga75pKIxaxvijKCOIYCGY3IMmHmSOsiqBiqnz8px6MyEH7TXaxb7M@9CxDryAGRKVYeTWitCT/CDGoxt9Fnp07oIE9@VuwMAgF6glYB2TX6f7Ta0r@g0Vs8bkIJUF7diyx/onlCxXiNjBXXZLCb@xd9k17M3wvBqgnNUw6C0H0ccwxmfBICmW8jmOgNKKiPAasxvRDndC5CDR5SSnHbRjv4HcXZMgqZDsU5swdPo4aS1t3QaS7Jm44x6LEhJdnTAdDkhFfzismVCGPZ4wck9waviAO4hxcjww2@mg9NhMZNKUbkrHp67MmtGmLUaxocjVrel3G0v6ZZYkVKiqyuay6vVA97OsQNNQYSJd06qcnYQ7p3nlecDtnSKV7@aX8@k1d4F/7Hll4rsV3NWT3cTL91dT8IfqXxC@cX9LzcX8Hzuf1MQecu2lBU@XPXPqtbGF9ruwpk/e6@N1Bn8sQQFBAf4q8iE4b9OBT3M4aedpvhVcbzH7QdoB0Er9TJsjTvHjvV2jT1cfpUPSnHvToOzrVfmSXu5BYn/G@oeE3@L68Ci5b9IFZl2fPgoy9Ma7zN9YqHVxmmWu9kRjkdUs3yITE6mIWHmWYi2GIkX@Ct0U5cVFFR24FWVZTr36006XFY1aYDd7yNXYp2ySqOZGY5OnzG9mfaCtjlBtwd47CO2mBYd0Z8qXxXS2mP@q6xOj/BWcooeLeXlW9kqVpUSWpMeZ/JOG/7hS/wM)

Output:

          `*
          0
         000
        00000
       0000000
      000000000
     00000000000
    0000000000000
   000000000000000
  00000000000000000
 0000000000000000000`

Hardcoded with 10:

`{(0..10).map{if(it<1)" ".repeat(10)+"*"
else " ".repeat(11-it)+"0".repeat(it*2-1)}.joinToString("\n")}`

Comment: You can to save some bytes: `{n:Int->(-1..n).map{if(it<0)"".padEnd(n)+"*"
else "".padEnd(n-it)+"0".repeat(it*2+1)}.joinToString("\n")}`

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 134 bytes

The tree is resizable.

```erlang
r(-1,_)->"";r(X,Y)->lists:duplicate(X," ")++lists:duplicate(Y,"0")++"\n"++r(X-1,Y+2).
t(X)->lists:duplicate(X-1," ")++"*\n"++r(X-1,1).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBCsIwDEDv/YqSU2Pb4bw5Yd@xoiJlVgnUOtqKn18jXkTMKbzkvZCjT1cbypxpqU20rGxvTmhHgF1Wk3G8Riq1DOfHEmn2NTAFCaj1L3cG1m8OhwRas80ppzfYiaqmfx2@f0qw@lJ67NrNU1L7I0o7CslD9@HyzMRSVVvkhxc)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), fixed height: 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¾17ÅÉ×'*š.c
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0D5D88OthzsPT1fXOrpQL/n/fwA)

**Variable height through input: <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**:

```
Î·ÍÅÉ×'*š.c
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cN@h7Yd7D7ce7jw8XV3r6EK95P//DU0B)

**Explanation:**

```python
¾             # Push 0 (push the counter_variable, which is 0 by default)
 17ÅÉ         # Push a list of the positive odd numbers <= 17: [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17]
     ×        # Repeat the 0 that many times as string:
              #  ["0", "000", "00000", ..., "00000000000000000"]
      '*š    '# Prepend a "*": ["*", "0", "000", "00000", ..., "00000000000000000"]
         .c   # Centralize each line by padding with leading spaces
              # (which also implicitly joins a list by newlines at the same time)
              # (after which it is output implicitly as result)

Î             # Push 0 and the input-integer
 ·            # Double the input
  Í           # Decrease it by 2
   ÅÉ×'*š.c  '# Same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, 128

```c
h=10;y,w,i,j;main(){for(y=-1;y<h;y++){w=1+max(y,0)*2;i=((h*2)-w)/2;for(j=0;j<i+w;j+1)printf(j<i?" ":y+1?"0":"*");printf("\n");}}
```

```
         *
         0
        000
       00000
      0000000
     000000000
    00000000000
   0000000000000
  000000000000000
 00000000000000000
0000000000000000000
```

`h` is the tree's height without the star.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
AÇçT êÃh* û
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=QcfnVCDqw2gqIPs)

```
AÇçT êÃh* û     :(Remove A to input the height instead)
A               :10
 Ç              :Map the range [0,A) (or [0,input))
  ç             :  Repeat
   T            :    0
     ê          :  Palindromise
      Ã         :End map
       h*       :Replace the first element with "*"
          û     :Centre pad with spaces to the length of the longest
                :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 57 bytes

```
/i/         /i*/> /
i0\/ \\0\/a\\a\/\/a\\a\/000\/>//>//>i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/Xz9TXwEG9DO19O0U9LkyDWL0FWJigGRiTExijD6MNjAACtnpg1Hm//8A)

Normally I would have another replacement for the escaped "/" in the loop bit, but it happens to be the same length without so why not.

Change the number of spaces in the first line, after the `/i/`. Technically, there is one less space that the 'size' but size 0, 1 etc aren't defined so I don't think it matters.