# Tips for golfing in Java

Tags: code-golf, tips, java

Are there any useful shortcuts that can be used in Java?

As shown below, `import` already adds at least 17 characters to a program.

```java
import java.io.*;
```

I understand that the simple solution would be to use another language, but it seems to be a real challenge to shorten Java programs.

---

Tips should be specific to Java: if they're applicable to most C-like languages, they belong in the more [general list of tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages).

Comment: `package` can be skipped.

Comment: In an answer, can't I just omit the imports assuming they are there?

Comment: @Fabricio Not unless the OP specifies so.

Comment: Best tip about golfing Java: don't use it. ;)

Comment: "I want to golf in java" good luck

Comment: JAVA 11: make use of the "var" type inference

Comment: @BitBeats Java 10, really

Answer (score 95):

- Use the most recent possible java. Java 8 lets you use lambda expressions, so use it if you need anything even *like* functional objects.
- Define shortened functions for things you use a lot. For instance, you have a hundred calls to `exampleClassInstance.doSomething(someParameter)`, define a new function `void d(ParameterType p){exampleClassInstance.doSomething(p)}` and use it to save yourself some characters.
- If you are using a particular long class name more than once, like

  ```java
  MyEventHandlerProxyQueueExecutorServiceCollectionAccessManagerFactory
  ```

  instead define a new class:

  ```java
  class X extends MyEventHandlerProxyQueueExecutorServiceCollectionAccessManagerFactory{}
  ```

  If you are only using one particular method of that class (but still need to instantiate it), you can define a shortened version inside the new class at the same time.
- Use function type parameters to shorten things, where possible, like this:

  ```java
  <T>void p(T o){System.out.println(o);}
  ```
- Use `for(;;)` instead of `while(true)`.
- Do not use access modifiers unless absolutely necessary.
- Do not use `final` for anything.
- Never put a block after a `for` loop (but a foreach loop `for(x:y)` is different). Additional statements should be placed inside the `for` statement itself, like `for(int i=0;i<m;a(i),b(++i))c(i);`.
- Use inline assignment, incrementation, instantiation. Use anonymous inline classes where appropriate. Use lambdas instead if possible. Nest function calls. Some functions are guaranteed to return their parent object, these ones are actually even *meant* to be chained together.
- Your `main` method `throws Exception`s, not catches them.
- `Error` is shorter than `Exception`. If for some reason you *really* need to `throw` messages up the stack, use an `Error`, even if it is perfectly normal situation.
- If some condition would require immediate termination, use `int a=1/0;` rather than `throw null;` or `System.exit(0);`. At run time, this throws an `ArithmeticException`.  If you already have a numeric variable in your code, use it instead. (If you already have `import static java.lang.System.*;`, go with `exit(0);`.)
- Instead of implementing interfaces, like `List<E>`, extend an immediate (or not-so-immediate, if there is any advantage to doing so at all) child class, like `AbstractList<E>`, which provides default implementations of most of the methods, and requires only the implementation of a few key pieces.
- Write your code out in longhand first, with newlines, indentation, and full variable names. Once you have working code, then you can shorten names, move declarations around, and add shortcut methods. By writing it out long to start, you give yourself more opportunity to simplify the program as a whole.
- Compare alternative optimizations to a piece of code, because the most optimal strategy can change dramatically with very small changes to the code. For instance:

  - If you have only up to two calls to `Arrays.sort(a)`, the most efficient way to is to call it with its fully qualified name, `java.util.Arrays.sort(a)`.
  - With three or more calls, it is more efficient to instead add a shortcut method `void s(int[]a){java.util.Arrays.sort(a);}`. This should still use the fully-qualified name in this case. (If you need more than one overload, you are probably doing it wrong.)
  - However, if your code needs to also copy an array at some point (usually done with a short `for` loop in golfing, in the absence of an easily-accessible library method), you can take advantage of `Arrays.copyOf` to do the task. When more than one method is used, and there are 3 or more calls, doing `import static java.util.Arrays.*;` is the most efficient way of referring to those methods. After that, only if you have more than 8 separate calls to `sort` should you be using a shortcut method for it, and only at 5 or more calls is a shortcut warranted for `copyOf`.

  The only real way of performing such analysis on code is to actually perform potential modifications on copies of the code, and then compare the results.
- Avoid using `someTypeValue.toString();` method, instead just append `someTypeValue+""`.
- If you do need windows, don't use Swing, use AWT (unless you really need something from Swing). Compare `import javax.swing.*;` and `import java.awt.*;`. Additionally, components in Swing have a `J` prepended to their name (`JFrame`, `JLabel`, etc), but components in AWT don't (`Frame`, `Label`, etc)

Answer (score 58):

**Use `interface` instead of `class`.**

In java 8, static methods were added to interfaces. In interfaces, all methods are public by default. Consequently

```java
class A{public static void main(String[]a){}}
```

can now be shortened to

```java
interface A{static void main(String[]a){}}
```

which is obviously shorter.

For example, [I used](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64567/32700) this feature in the [Hello, World!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422/32700) challenge.

Comment: I didn't know that! +1, nice trick

Comment: Yay, less boilerplate!

Comment: [I have to partially disagree](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140181/16236) (also, [I beat you](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/140175#140175) in the "Hello, World!" challenge, using that technique).

Comment: I would use a static initializer...needs no interface, no public and no main...in combination with enum...

Answer (score 41):

With [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) you can "cast" a parameter to an array of the same type:

```java
void f(String...x){
    x=x[0].split("someregex");
    // some code using the array
}
```

instead of

```java
void f(String s){
    String[]x=s.split("someregex");
    // some code using the array
}
```

Answer (score 37):

With a **static import**:

```java
import static java.lang.System.out;
// even shorter (thanks to Johannes Kuhn):
import static java.lang.System.*;
```

you can save some boilerplate later, but you need multiple invocations to reach a payoff:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {
    out.println ("foo");    
    out.println ("bar");    
    out.println ("baz");    
}
```

Comment: :O. You can do this?! And all this time I thought that this was impossible in `Java`!

Comment: you can even use `import static java.lang.System.*`.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but in Java 10 you can now do `var o=System.out;` which only needs to be used twice before it pays off

Comment: @LukeStevens: Well, maybe you find some other improvements, possible with Java10, and form a separate answer around Java10?

Comment: @LukeStevens Would `var o=System.out.println` work?

Comment: @MilkyWay90: I understand it this way:`var o=System.out; o.println(foo);o.println(bar);`

Answer (score 33):

The argument to `main` doesn't have to be called `args`, and you can cut some whitespace:

```java
public static void main(String[]a){}
```

will do just fine.

Comment: Do answers need to include the main function if it doesn't explicitly state to write a full program?  I've been using lambda expressions as answers.

Comment: @Makotosan No they don't; Lambdas are usually fine.

Answer (score 30):

If you ever have to use the boolean expressions `true` or `false`, replace them with `1>0` and `1<0` respectively.

For example:

```java
boolean found=false;
for(i=0; i<10; i++) if(a[i]==42) found=true;
```

This linear search example can be reduced to

```java
boolean f=1<0;
for(i=0;i<10;)if(a[i++]==42)f=1>0;
```

Comment: If you're going to need a lot of `true/false`, just add `boolean t=1>0,f=1<0;`. Then instead of `1>0`, use `t` and save two chars per use. Payoff over `1>0` method comes at 10 uses.

Comment: @Geobits: `boolean t=1>0,f=!t;` - one char shorter!

Comment: The example is not really good. In this case and many(!) others you can avoid using `true`/`false` directly anyway: `f|=a[i++]==42;` saves quite a lot.

Comment: @IngoBürk True. When I was writing this I was mostly thinking about library functions that uses `boolean`, but since I couldn't come up with any examples at the time of writing (I don't usually code in Java) I just wrote a simple example.

Comment: @Geobits not too familiar with java but could you just define 1 and use t and !t (again I dont know Java, just curious)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw if you do `int t = 1;` you'll get `error: bad operand type int for unary operator '!'`. If you do `boolean t = 1;` you'll get `error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean`

Comment: @ace sorry that should have read "Could you just define one*" haha, as in one variable (t or f). My internet slang has ruined me xD

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Well then of course you can. It depends on how many times `false` has to be used. If you use it, say, only 1 to 2 times, while you use `true` a lot, then certainly your suggestion would be useful. But not if you need to use it for, say, 100 times.

Comment: There are a lot of languages in which you can do this.

Answer (score 26):

This may seem obvious, but there are shorter options for some `Math` functions:

```java
a=Math.max(b,c);
a=b>c?b:c;

a=Math.min(b,c);
a=b<c?b:c;

a=Math.abs(b);
a=b<0?-b:b;
(In certain situations, (a|1)%2*a, may be shorter)

a=Math.round(b);
a=(int)(b+.5);          // watch for precision loss if it matters
```

Answer (score 25):

If you are going to be using some method a lot, assign its resident class to a variable. For example, assign `System.out` to a variable:

```java
java.io.PrintStream o=System.out;
//now I can call o.print() or o.println() to the same effect as System.out.println()
```

Also for `Integer.parseInt()`:

```java
Integer i=1;
i.parseInt("some string");
```

This will almost surely trigger an ide warning about "accessing static method from variable"

Comment: `((Integer)1).parseInt("1")` works too.

Comment: @carusocomputing `new Integer("1")` is even shorter. But what Justin meant with his answer is that you can reuse variables you already have for static calls. [As I explain at the bottom of this answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84753/52210)

Comment: Maybe in vombination with `var`...

Answer (score 24):

Rather than using the `import static java.lang.System.*` technique to save on `println()` statements, I've found that defining the following method is much more effective at saving characters:

```java
static<T>void p(T p){
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

This is because it can be invoked as `p(myString)` rather than `out.println(myString)` which has a much quicker and more dramatic character payoff.

Comment: The usage of<T> to  avoid having to type Object is a really neat touch!

Answer (score 22):

## Some small code-golfing tips

These tips were a bit too small for a separated answers, so I will use this answer for very small codegolfing tips that I found or came up with, and aren't mentioned in the other tips yet:

#### Removing the last character of a String:

```java
// I used to do something like this:
s.substring(0,s.length()-1)     // 27 bytes

// But this is shorter:
s.replaceAll(".$","")           // 21 bytes
```

In some cases you know what the last character is beforehand, and you also know this character only occurs once in the String. In that case you can use `.split` instead:

```java
// As example: "100%" to "100"
s.split("%")[0]                 // 15 bytes
```

#### Encoding shortcuts:

```java
// When you want to get the UTF-8 bytes I used to do this:
s.getBytes("UTF-8");     // 20 bytes

// But you can also use "UTF8" for the same result:
s.getBytes("UTF8");      // 19 bytes
```

All encodings have a canonical name used in the `java.nio` API, as well as a canonical name used in the `java.io` and `java.lang` APIs. [Here is a full list of all supported encodings in Java.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) So always use the shortest of the two; the second is usually shorter (like `UTF-8` vs `utf8`, `Windows-1252` vs `Cp1252`, etc.), but not always (`UTF-16BE` vs `UnicodeBigUnmarked`).

#### Random boolean:

```java
// You could do something like this:
new java.util.Random().nextBoolean()     // 36 bytes

// But as mentioned before in @Geobits' answer, Math.random() doesn't require an import:
Math.random()<.5                         // 16 bytes
```

#### Primes:

There are a lot of different ways to check for primes or get all primes. [@SaraJ's answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181611/52210) is the shortest for positive integers (\$\geq1\$), and *@primo*'s method is the shortest for integers \$\geq2\$.

```java
// Check if n (≥ 1) is a prime (@SaraJ's method):
n->{int i=1;for(;n%++i%n>0;);return n==i;}

// Check if n (≥ 2) is a prime (@primo's method):
n->{int i=n;for(;n%--i>0;);return i<2;}
```

These prime checks can be modified to loop over primes. Here doing so with *@SaraJ*'s approach for example:

```java
v->{for(int n=2,i;;){for(i=1;n%++i%n>0;);if(n++==i)/*do something with prime `i` here*/;}}
```

NOTE: Usually you can merge it with other existing loops depending on how you want to use it, so you won't need a separate method. This saved a lot of bytes in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128774/52210) for example.

#### Integer truncation instead of Math.floor/Math.ceil:

If you are using ***positive*** doubles/floats and you want to `floor` them, don't use `Math.floor` but use an `(int)`-cast instead (since Java truncates on integers):

```java
double d = 54.99;

int n=(int)Math.floor(d);     // 25 bytes

int m=(int)d;                 // 13 bytes

// Outputs 54 for both
```

The same trick can be applied to ***negative*** doubles/floats you want to `ceil` instead:

```java
double d = -54.99;

int n=(int)Math.ceil(d);     // 24 bytes

int m=(int)d;                // 13 bytes

// Outputs -54 for both
```

#### Use `&1` instead of `%2` to get rid of parenthesis:

Because the [Operator Precedence](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) of `&` is lower than default arithmetic operators like `*/+-` and `%`, you can get rid of parenthesis in some cases.

```java
// So instead of this:
(i+j)%2     // 7 bytes

// Use this:
i+j&1       // 5 bytes
```

Note that this doesn't really help in boolean-checks, because then you'd still need parenthesis, they're just moved a bit:

```java
(i+j)%2<1    // 9 bytes
(i+j&1)<1    // 9 bytes
```

#### BigIntegers and creating variables for static method calls:

When using BigIntegers, only create it once which you can then re-use. As you may know, BigInteger contains static fields for `ZERO`, `ONE` and `TEN`. So when you only use those three, you don't need an `import` but can use `java.Math.BigInteger` directly.

```java
// So instead of this:
import java.math.BigInteger.*;
BigInteger a=BigInteger.ONE,b=BigInteger.ZERO;                // 76 bytes

// or this:
java.math.BigInteger a=java.math.BigInteger.ONE,b=a.ZERO;     // 57 bytes

// Use this:
java.math.BigInteger t=null,a=t.ONE,b=t.ZERO;                 // 45 bytes
```

NOTE: You have to use `=null` so `t` is initialized in order to use `t.`.

Sometimes you can add multiple BigIntegers to create another to save bytes. So let's say you want to have the BigIntegers `1,10,12` for some reason:

```java
// So instead of this:
BigInteger t=null,a=t.ONE,b=t.TEN,c=new BigInteger(12);     // 55 bytes

// Use this:
BigInteger t=null,a=t.ONE,b=t.TEN,c=b.add(a).add(a);        // 52 bytes
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the trick with `BigInteger t=null;` for it's static method calls can also be used with other classes.
For example, [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1525/52210) from 2011 can be golfed:

```java
// 173 bytes:
import java.util.*;class g{public static void main(String[]p){String[]a=p[0].split(""),b=p[1].split("");Arrays.sort(a);Arrays.sort(b);System.out.print(Arrays.equals(a,b));}}

// 163 bytes
class g{public static void main(String[]p){java.util.Arrays x=null;String[]a=p[0].split(""),b=p[1].split("");x.sort(a);x.sort(b);System.out.print(x.equals(a,b));}}
```

#### `getBytes()` instead of `toCharArray()`

When you want to loop over the characters of a String, you'll usually do this:

```java
for(char c:s.toCharArray())    // 27 bytes
// or this:
for(String c:s.split(""))      // 25 bytes
```

Looping over the characters can be useful when printing them, or appending them to a String, or something similar.

However, if you only use the chars for some unicode-number calculations, you can replace the `char` with `int`, AND you can replace `toCharArray()` with `getBytes()`:

```java
for(int c:s.getBytes())        // 23 bytes
```

Or even shorter in Java 8+:

```java
s.chars().forEach(c->...)      // 22 bytes
```

In Java 10+ looping over the character to print can now also be done in 22 bytes:

```java
for(var c:s.split(""))         // 22 bytes
```

#### Random item from a `List`:

```java
List l=...;

// When we have an `import java.util.*;` in our code, shuffling is shortest:
return l.get(new Random().nextInt(l.size()));     // 45 bytes
return l.get((int)(Math.random()*l.size()));      // 44 bytes
Collections.shuffle(l);return l.get(0);           // 39 bytes

// When we don't have an `import java.util.*` in our code, `Math.random` is shortest:
return l.get(new java.util.Random().nextInt(l.size()));     // 55 bytes
return l.get((int)(Math.random()*l.size()));                // 44 bytes
java.util.Collections.shuffle(l);return l.get(0);           // 49 bytes
```

#### Check if a String contains leading/trailing spaces

```java
String s=...;

// I used to use a regex like this:
s.matches(" .*|.* ")     // 20 bytes
// But this is shorter:
!s.trim().equals(s)      // 19 bytes
// And this is even shorter due to a nice feature of String#trim:
s!=s.trim()              // 11 bytes
```

Why does this work, when `!=` on Strings is to check for reference instead of value in Java? Because [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) will return "*A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or **this string if it has no leading or trailing white space**.*" I've used this, after someone suggested this to me, in [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143387/52210).

#### Palindrome:

To check if a String is a palindrome (keeping in mind both even and odd lengths of Strings), this is the shortest (`.contains` works here because we know both the String itself and its reversed form are of equal length):

```java
String s=...;
s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse())    // 41 bytes
```

`.contains(...)` instead of `.equals(...+"")` thanks to [*@assylias*'s comment here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153249/list-all-palindromic-prime-dates-between-0000-01-01-and-99999-12-31/153255#comment374815_153255).

#### Either is 0, or both are 0?

I think most already know this one: if you want to check if either `a` or `b` is zero, multiply instead to save bytes:

```java
a==0|b==0    // 9 bytes
a*b==0       // 6 bytes
```

And if you want to check if both `a` and `b` are zero, you could use a bitwise-OR, or add them together if they are always positive:

```java
a==0&b==0    // 9 bytes
(a|b)==0     // 8 bytes (if either `a`, `b` or both can be negative)
a+b<1        // 5 bytes (this only works if neither `a` nor `b` can be negative)
```

#### Even = 1, odd = -1; or vice-versa

```java
// even = 1; odd = -1:
n%2<1?1:-1        // 10 bytes
1-n%2*2           // 7 bytes

// even = -1; odd = 1:
n%2<1?-1:1        // 10 bytes
n%2*2-1           // 7 bytes
```

The reason I add this was after seeing `k+(k%2<1?1:-1)` in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64269/52210):

```java
k+(k%2<1?1:-1)    // 14 bytes

// This would already have been shorter:
k%2<1?k+1:k-1     // 13 bytes

// But it can also be:
k%2*-2-~k         // 9 bytes
```

#### Loop `n` times in Full Program

If we have a challenge where a full program is mandatory, and we need to loop a specific amount of times, we can do the following:

```java
// instead of:
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(int n=50;n-->0;)/*do something*/}}  // 78 bytes
// we could do:
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(M m:new M[50])/*do something*/}}    // 76 bytes
```

The same applies when we have to take this range as input:

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(int n=new Byte(a[0]);n-->0;)/*do something*/}}  // 90 bytes
interface M{static void main(String[]a){for(M m:new M[new Byte(a[0])])/*do something*/}}    // 88 bytes
```

Credit to [*@JackAmmo* in this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/67921/what-is-the-smallest-positive-base-10-integer-that-can-be-printed-by-a-program-s#comment165935_67983).

#### try-finally instead of try-catch(Exception e), and when/how to use it

If you have to catch and ignore an Exception, in most cases it's shorter to use `finally{...;}` instead of `catch(Exception){}`. Some examples:

When you want to return the result as soon as you hit an error:

```java
try{...}catch(Exception e){return ...;}    // 33 bytes
try{...}finally{return ...;}               // 22 bytes
```

I've used this initially to save bytes in [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153993/52210) (credit for the indirect golf goes to *@KamilDrakari*). In this challenge we have to loop diagonally over an NxM matrix, so we have to determine whether the amount of columns or amount of rows is the lowest as our maximum in the for-loop (which is quite expensive in terms of bytes: `i<Math.min(a.length,a[0].length)`). So, simply catching the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` using `catch-finally` is shorter than this check, and thus saves bytes:

```java
int[] a = ...;

int r=0,i=0;for(;i<Math.min(a.length,a[0].length);)r=...i++...;return r;    // 66 bytes

int r=0,i=0;try{for(;;)r=...i++...;}finally{return r;}                      // 48 bytes
```

This also works with a void `return;`, like this:

```java
try{...}catch(Exception e){}  // 25 bytes
try{...}finally{return;}      // 21 bytes
```

Which actually saved an additional byte in that same linked answer above by putting the answer in the very first cell, like [*@KamilDrakari* does in his C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154011/52210) as well:

```java
m->{try{for(...);}finally{return;}}
```

But what about a try-catch where you don't want to immediately return? Unfortunately, you can't have a completely empty `finally{}` block as alternative to catch an Exception. You can however still use it inside a loop by using `continue` (or `break`) as alternatives. Here an example where we want to continue with the next iteration of the loop when an Exception occurs:

```java
for(...)try{...}catch(Exception e){}  // 30 bytes
for(...)try{...}finally{continue;}    // 28 bytes
```

I've used this approach in [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154563/52210) to save 2 bytes.

So when you can use a `return`, `continue` or `break`, it's always better to use `try{...}finally{...;}` instead of `try{...}catch(Exception e){}`. And in most cases, especially when checking boundaries of matrices, it's shorter to `try-finally` any `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions`, instead of doing manual checks to see whether the indices are still in bounds.

#### Math.pow(2,n)

When you want a power of 2, a bit-wise approach is much shorter:

```java
(int)Math.pow(2,n)    // 16 bytes
(1<<n)                // 6 bytes
```

#### Combining bit-wise and logical checks instead of using parenthesis

I think it is well-known by now that `&` and `|` can be used instead of `&&` and `||` in Java (boolean) logical checks. In some cases you'd still want to use `&&` instead of `&` to prevent errors though, like `index >= 0 && array[index].doSomething`. If the `&&` would be changed to `&` here, it will still evaluate the part where it uses the index in the array, causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, hence the use of `&&` in this case instead of `&`.

So far the basics of `&&`/`||` vs `&`/`|` in Java.

When you want to check `(A or B) and C`, the shortest might seem to use the bit-wise operators like this:

```java
(A|B)&C    // 7 bytes
```

However, because the bit-wise operators have [operator precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) over the logical checks, you can combine both to save a byte here:

```java
A|B&&C     // 6 bytes
```

#### Use `n+=...-n` instead of `(long)...`

When you have a long as both in and output in a lambda, for example when using `Math.pow`, you can save a byte by using `n+=...-n` instead of `(long)...`.
For example:

```java
n->(long)Math.pow(10,n)    // 23 bytes
n->n+=Math.pow(10,n)-n     // 22 bytes
```

This saved a byte in [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161281/make-an-emergency-corridor/161346#161346), and even two bytes by combining `-n-1` to `+~n` in [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/163737/return-the-highest-possible-placement-value-based-on-the-input/163783#163783).

Comment: More generally for your last point, you can access/invoke static members from a non-static context such as an instance of the object.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire [Doesn't seem to work..](https://tio.run/##dY6xCoMwFEV3v@KNZjBVaIdWbIdCt06OpUM0ImljIiYKWvx2GyOoCE7vcc6Fez@kIZ4sM/Gh32FIOVEKnoSJnwNQ1glnKShNtDmNZBQKo9xYV0zkrzeQKldoTAJQacIZdBDB6YjP53BNW0MDH/tB6Fh8OMCDS1ldpix4V/NsjM2PJvCtYUIDiVxzUBfOJJlIO5G4VTorsKw1Ls1EzYVL0K5K0DLnnjF@W885bcwyJ5jL08hzbb3XoWUSnWm7353uK2pV7/TD8Ac) (They are flooring as well.)

Comment: I do not understand your ceil tip. Why would you want to ceil `positive integers`? Also, I am not sure if the ceil implementation [works](https://tio.run/##fY/NCsIwEITP9imGnhKKoT2LD@DBUz0pIrGJGhuT0qyKlD57jcWDgrinYX@@2TnLm5z6RruzqofmuremQmVlCFhK49AFkhRbN28U1kz5uKGheJdMzAGMGUdcZQXmc4x6KekkKm0sU5yjfATSF@GvJJo2jq1j6epkAqg1VY27b@sA75BmKktFymfJRNug8b9@URcE5XWA8zRiv6n9O9hnmEuMx8r4iDtutjuOblgzFLnIC8SLUb/M@Gzo@@EJ).

Comment: I also think your floor tip should say `If you are using positive doubles / floats` instead of `If you are using positive integers`, as you do not have to floor integers.

Comment: `since Java automatically floors on integers`; I think the proper term is _truncation_, not _flooring_.

Comment: Ah, well then nevermind.

Comment: Another Palindrome strategy `String t="";for(int i=s.length();--i>=0;t+=s.charAt(i));return s.equals(t);`

Comment: @RobertoGraham Hmm, that's actually shorter. Oh, and you can golf `--i>=0` to `i-->0` as well. Thanks, will edit it.

Comment: @RobertoGraham I actually copied my original code from the wrong challenge.. Just `s.equals(new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+"")` is enough.

Comment: Fun (longer) Java 8 one: `s.equals(s.chars().mapToObj(i->""+(char)i).reduce((q,w)->w+q).get())`

Comment: Could `i>0&(i+j&1<1)` not be golfed to `i>0&&i+j&1<1` (regarding the "Use &1 instead of %2 to get rid of parenthesis" paragraph)?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I'm afraid not. In Java it will see the `i+j&1<1` part as `i+j` and `1<1`, so it will complain `&` is a bad binary operator (since `i+j` is an integer, and `1<1` is a boolean). [Here the error on TIO for this particular code snippet.](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNSsn@/z85J7G4WME3MTOvmktBoaA0KSczWaG4JLEESJXlZ6Yo5AKlNIJLijLz0qNjFRI1QcoUFDLzShQybQ11smyNrMECwZXFJam5evmlJXoFQLUlOXkamXYGamqZ2llqhjaGmiBVtVy1//8DAA) I do now realize my tip is incorrect, because the `<1` part doesn't work for that same reason.. >.> My bad, thanks for the indirect correction.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh. That then, however, also applies to your original snippet.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Should be fixed now. As I mentioned in the edited comment above, thanks for the indirect correction.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, now it looks fixed. Did not properly read your comment, thus the duplication. You could extend the tip by mentioning a similiar approach for all powers-of-two-moduli (`(a+b)%(1<<n)` <-> `a+b&((1<<n)-1)`), not exceeding the integer's limit.

Comment: Primes: `n->{int i=n;for(;n%--i>0;);return i%n<2;}` for -1.

Comment: @primo Oh nice. But isn't the `%n` obsolete in this case and it's actually -3? For input `n=1` it errors due to a division by zero error (which might not make this approach suitable to use everywhere), but because of that there is no need to use `%n`, is there?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you're right, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 17):

Don't use `public class`. The main method needs to be public, but its class doesn't. This code works:

```java
class S{public static void main(String[]a){System.out.println("works");}}
```

You may run `java S` even though `class S` is not a public class.  (*Update:* I was using Java 7 when I wrote this tip.  In Java 8, [your main method should be in an interface](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64713/4065).  In Java 5 or 6, [your main method should be in an enum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140181/4065).)

Plenty of Java programmers don't know this! About half the answers to [a Stack Overflow question about main in non-public class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12524322/3614563) wrongly claim that the main method must be in a public class. Now you know better. Delete the `public` in `public class` and save 7 characters.

Comment: Unless you are targeting a Java prior to 1.8, the construct `interface s{static void main(String[]...` is shorter. If you must have a compilable source file and main method. Because in a Java 1.8 interface, all methods are public so you can skip the modifier on the method(s).

Comment: I have not recently used Java, so my answer is getting outdated. I forgot that interfaces can have methods in Java 8.

Comment: I didn't learn it from programming; I learned it from golfing :)

Answer (score 17):

You don't have to use `Character.toLowerCase(char c)`. Instead use `(c|32)`. Instead of `Character.toUpperCase(char c)` use `(c&95)`. This only works with ASCII letters.

Comment: `c|~32` would tend to result in -1... better to use `c-32`.

Comment: @feersum That would not work if you wanted to make an upper case letter upper case.

Comment: Late to the party: `c&95` for uppercase.

Answer (score 17):

If you need `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647), use `-1>>>1`. `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648) is better written `1<<31`.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to grab *a number* from an argument (or any other string), normally you see something like:

```java
public static void main(String[]a){
    int n=Integer.valueOf(a[0]);
    ...
}
```

Many times, you don't *need* an `Integer`. Plenty of challenges don't use large numbers. Since `Short` and `Byte` will both unbox to an `int`, use the more appropriate `valueOf()` instead and save a couple bytes.

Keep your actual *variable* as an `int`, though, since it's shorter than both `byte` and `short`:

```java
int n=Byte.valueOf(a[0]);
```

If you need to do this for multiple numbers, you can combine with [this method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16089/14215):

```java
Byte b=1;
int n=b.valueOf(a[0]),m=b.valueOf(a[1])...
```

Comment: `int n=new Byte(a[0]);` is three shorter. If the number might be larger, use `long n=new Long(a[0])`, it's still better than `int`s in most cases.

Answer (score 15):

## Convert String to number

There are multiple ways to convert a String to an numeric value:

```java
String s = "12";
```

*ABC.parseABC*:

```java
Short.parseShort(s); // 20 bytes
Integer.parseInt(s); // 20 bytes
Long.parseLong(s);   // 18 bytes
```

*ABC.valueOf*:

```java
Short.valueOf(s);    // 17 bytes
Integer.valueOf(s);  // 19 bytes
Long.valueOf(s);     // 16 bytes
```

*ABC.decode*:

```java
// Note: does not work for numeric values with leading zeros,
// since these will be converted to octal numbers instead
Short.decode(s);     // 16 bytes
Integer.decode(s);   // 18 bytes
Long.decode(s);      // 15 bytes
```

*new ABC*:

```java
new Short(s);        // 13 bytes
new Integer(s);      // 15 bytes
new Long(s);         // 12 bytes
```

So, for code-golfing, it's best to use the constructor when converting a String to a numeric value.

The same applies to `Double`; `Float`; and `Byte`.

---

This doesn't always apply when you can re-use an already present primitive as object.
As example, let's say we have the following code:

```java
// NOTE: Pretty bad example, because changing the short to int would probably be shorter..
//       but it's just an example to get the point across

short f(short i,String s){
  short r=new Short(s);  // 21 bytes
  ... // Do something with both shorts
}
```

You can use `.decode` instead of the shorter constructor by re-using the parameter as object:

```java
short f(Short i,String s){   // Note the short parameter has changed to Short here
  short r=i.decode(s);   // 20 bytes
  ... // Do something with both shorts
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For golfing that doesn't require input, you can use static blocks, and run it just fine without any main method, just compile it with Java 6.

```java
public class StaticExample{
    static {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to compile and run it? This block is run when the class gets loaded by the class loader. But the class loader won't load anything until it knows of a class with a main method.

Comment: @Cruncher You can get around that by yourself telling `java` on the command line/in a manifest file which class to load.

Comment: @AJMansfield I'm pretty sure the manifest file is to tell java which class has main. If it doesn't have main in it, it shouldn't load it

Comment: @Cruncher, this worked with Java 6. Java 7 changed the way it works.

Comment: Throws an exception at the end but it works! Even in Java 7

Comment: @JopVernooij If you don't want to have an exception thrown to your face, you can system.exit(), but you'll waste characters, no golf challenge ever asks you to avoid exceptions ;)

Answer (score 13):

We all know about the bitwise xor (`^`), but it is also a logical xor.

So `(a||b)&&!(a&&b)` simply becomes `a^b`.

Now we can use xor.

[Additionally](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java#comment56317_25950), the operators `|` and `&` [also work](http://ideone.com/rG4XIq), just remember that operator precedence changes.

Comment: As long as you remember precedence, [you can use](http://ideone.com/rG4XIq) `&` and `|` also. It might be useful if your conditions are already in parentheses, or if you're already working with booleans.

Comment: If you need a (much) lower precedence, you can use `!=` instead of `^` for xor, and `==` for xnor

Answer (score 11):

**Don't use `Random`!**

*In general,* if you need random numbers, [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) is a horrible way to go about it*. Much better to use [`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) instead. To use `Random`, you need to do this (let's say we need an `int`):

```java
import java.util.*;
Random r=new Random();
a=r.nextInt(9);
b=r.nextInt(9);
```

Compare that to:

```java
a=(int)(Math.random()*9);
b=(int)(Math.random()*9);
```

and:

```java
int r(int m){return(int)(Math.random()*m);}
a=r(9);
b=r(9);
```

The first method takes `41+15n` characters (`n` is number of calls).
The second is `25n` characters, and the third is `43+7n`.

So, if you only need it once or twice, use the inline `Math.random()` method. For three or more calls, you'll save by using a function. Either one saves characters on the *first use* over `Random`.

---

If you're already using `Math.random()` for `double`, remember that at four uses, it's still a savings to pull it out into:

```java
double r(){return Math.random();}
```

For 33 characters, you'll save 10 on each call to `r()`

---

**Update**

If you need an integer and want to save on casting, *don't cast it!* Java auto-casts if you do an operation instead of an assignment. Compare:

```java
a=(int)(Math.random()*9);
a=9;a*=Math.random();
```

<sup>* *Unless you have to seed the PRNG for predictable results. Then, I don't see much of a way around it.*</sup>

Comment: Don't forget about [`Random#nextGaussian`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian%28%29) though.

Comment: @Quincunx True, doing the math to get a good normal distribution would lose you any savings you got. I'll just refer to that as the exception that proves the rule ;)

Comment: Note that `(int)(Math.random()*9)` has a very small modulo bias, because `Math.random()` returns 2**53 possible values, and 2**53 is not a multiple of 9. The probability of each number is within 1/9 plus or minus 5/(9*2**53), an error so small, it is almost exactly 1/9.

Comment: @kernigh Right, I was using `9` just as an example, it could be anything. I'm relatively sure that `nextInt()` (or any other `Random` method) has a small bias as well, just due to how Java's PRNG works.

Comment: In rare cases its actually better to extend random.

Comment: Something related for when you want a random boolean: instead of `new java.util.Random().nextBoolean()` you can use `Math.random()<.5`.

Answer (score 11):

## Don't be afraid to use scientific notation

If you are dealing with doubles, or floats, you can use scientific notation for numbers. So instead of writing `double a=1000` you can change it to `double a=1e3` to save 1 byte.

Answer (score 10):

## Try using `int` instead of `boolean`

In some cases I've found that it's shorter to return an integer value from a method that would normally return a boolean, similarly to what might be done in C programs.

Right off the bat `int` is 4 bytes shorter than `boolean`. Each time you write `return 0` instead of `return 1<0`, you save an additional 2 bytes and the same for `return 1`  over `return 1>0`.

The pitfall here is that each time you want to use the return value directly as a boolean, it costs 2 bytes (`if(p(n))` v. `if(p(n)>0)`). This can be made up for by use of boolean arithmetic. Given a contrived scenario where you want to write

```java
void a(int[]t){t[0]+=p(n)?10:0;}
```

you can instead write

```java
void a(int[]t){t[0]+=p(n)*10;}
```

in order to save 2 bytes.

Comment: I do this pretty often when golfing, but keep in mind that the [general consensus](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/14215) is that `0` and `1` don't constitute false/true in Java (and the JLS doesn't consider them that way either). So if the golf is specifically asking for truthy/falsy, you need to booleanize it (and, unfortunately, make it a `boolean` function, throwing even more bytes at it).

Comment: `t[0]+=p(n):10?0;` Is this even valid?

Comment: @dorukayhan no, it is meant to be `t[0]+=p(n)?10:0;`. (I edited it.)

Comment: @Geobits has this concensus changed? I was recently advised to use 0/1 for false/true

Comment: @simonalexander2005 I've been away for a couple years, so I'm not the best person to answer that. It may be worth bringing up on Meta, or maybe not. If you do it and get downvoted for it, you'll know ;)

Comment: @simonalexander2005 for questions asking for true/false the consensus still holds. However, many questions now only require that two distinct values are returned without requiring true or false explicitly

Answer (score 9):

If you use **enum instead of class**, you save one character.

```java
enum NoClass {
    F, G, H;    
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    }
}
```

But you have to introduce at least one enum instance (F, G, H in this example) which have to payoff themselves.

Comment: Seems you don't need any enum instances. I did `enum M{;public static void main(String[]a){...}` with no problems.

Comment: @Danny But then it doesn't save any characters. `class M{` is exactly the same length as `enum M{;`. In that case, I'd go with the `class` because it is prettier (IMO)

Comment: at least for me `enum{` worked without a `;` after; its only the IDE moaning that there is a error butthe compiler accepts it

Comment: @masterX244 What compiler/version? Mine throws a tantrum and won't do it.

Comment: worked on java 1.7 for me (appeared s, ned to investigate further cause with a update to .8 it stopped working)

Comment: @masterX244 For me, both OpenJDK 6 and 7 refuse to compile with the message `<identifier> expected`

Comment: @14mRh4X0r mystery error that it appeared to work for me, need to dig deeper :(

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you would consider this 'pure' Java, but [Processing](http://www.processing.org) allows you to create programs with little initial setup (completed automatically).

For console output, you can have something as simple as:

```
println("hi"); //done
```

for graphical output, a little more:

```
void setup() {
  size(640,480);
}
void draw() {
  fill(255,0,0); //color used to fill shapes
  rect(50,50,25,25); //25x25 pixel square at x=50,y=50
}
```

Comment: By the way, you do not even have to call `size` at all; it will default to a 100 by 100 pixel square. In most OSes, the frame around it will be about twice that large, with the square centered and the rest of the area filled with content taken from the desktop.

Comment: For graphical output, if you don't need animation, you can just write everything outside of `setup()` and `draw()` to use "static mode". You can also use 6-digit hex colors and the interpreter will change them, which sometimes pays off (`#FF8000` < `255,128,0`), and if you're using greyscale only one number needs to be specified (`255` < `255,255,255`)

Answer (score 8):

### Shortening returning

You can shorten return statements of strings by a byte with:

```
return "something";
```

to

```
return"something";
```

And, if you happen to begin your return statement with a parenthesis, you can do the same thing with them:

```
return (1+taxRate)*value;
```

to

```
return(1+taxRate)*value;
```

I guess quotes are considered like parentheticals? I actually picked this up through AppleScript, funnily enough, and thought it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Same applies to number signs, like `return-n;` instead of `return -n;` or `return~n;` instead of `return ~n;`. As well as single instead of double quotes: `return'A';`

Comment: Basically, works for anything which can't be part of an identifier (i.e. non-letter and non-digit).

Answer (score 8):

## Use Java 10's `var`

If you define a single variable of a specific type, use `var`.

#### Examples

```
var i=0;                        // int
var l=0L;                       // long
var s="";                       // String
var a=new int[]{1,2,3};         // int[]
var i=java.math.BigInteger.ONE; // BigInteger
var m=new java.util.HashMap();  // HashMap
var i=3+"abc".length()          // int
var a="a b c".split(" ");       // String[]
for(var a:"a b c".split(" "))   // String
```

#### Not usable in any of the following examples

`var` cannot be used in many examples

```
var i=1,j=2;           // only one variable is accepted at a time
var a={1,2,3};         // arrays must be explicitly declared
var f=a->a+" ";        // can't know what type a is.
var f=String::replace; // method references aren't properly inferred (weirdly, though)
```

Comment: RE why this doesn't work with method references, note that there are standard functional interfaces for only a small set of signatures (and methods can throw checked exceptions).

Comment: [One relevant StackOverflow post on the topic of var's method reference limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578603).

Comment: @Jakob Because while they may be "standard', they're not special to the compiler afaik. Suppose you have a method returning a boolean. Should the type be inferred as a `Function<T, Boolean>` or a `Predicate<T>`?

Answer (score 7):

## Avoid `StringBuilder`s

Appending stuff to a `String` takes up much fewer bytes.

```
// s is a StringBuilder
s.append("Hello, World!");

// S is a String
S+="Hello, World!";
```

If you have to reverse a string and print it right away, use a `StringBuffer`.

```
System.out.print(new StringBuilder("Hello, World!").reverse());
System.out.print(new StringBuffer("Hello, World!").reverse()); // Note that you can omit toString() when printing a non-String object
```

If you have to reverse a string and then do something else than printing it, use a `for`each loop.

```
String b=new StringBuffer("Hello, World!").reverse().toString();
String B="";for(String c:"Hello, World!".split(""))B=c+B;
```

Comment: A foreach loop is shorter than `StringBuffer`for reversing strings. `String b="";for(char c:"Hello, World!".toCharArray()){b=c+b;}`

Comment: You should also remove the `{}` from that foreach loop if you're going to use that method.

Comment: Save 2 bytes using `String s:"".split("")` instead of `char c:"".toCharArray()`.

Comment: If you have `java.util.stream.Stream` already imported, and if you need to chain another call to the result (like `B.chartAt(42)`) or if you just need to pass the result to a function (like `f(B)`), then using `for(:)` is equall to `Stream.of("Hello, World!".split("")).reduce("",(a,b)->b+a)`.

Comment: Both lines in your example with the for-each can be golfed. First one can become: `String b=new StringBuffer("Hello, World!").reverse()+"";` (`.toString` replaced with `+""`), and your second line can become: `String B="";for(String c:"Hello, World!".split(""))B=c+B;` (`char` to `String` and `.toCharArray()` to `.split("")`).

Comment: Hmm, you can replace `.toString()` with `+""` in your last example, so using `StringBuffer#reverse` is actually 1 byte shorter than the for-each loop..

Answer (score 7):

## Use `new Stack()` when you need basic `List` functionality

When you need a `java.util.List` (for example when you want to `.add(Object)`, `.remove(Object)`, `java.util.Collections.shuffle(java.util.Collection)`, etc.), I used to use `java.util.ArrayList` in most of my answers. But I was recently tipped to use `java.util.Vector` instead, and `java.util.Stack` is even shorter:

```java
import java.util.*;

List a=new ArrayList();   // 23 bytes
List b=new Vector();      // 20 bytes
List c=new Stack();       // 19 bytes
```

Answer (score 7):

## Shortest full program templates.

#### Introduction

The [Java spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) never ever say that a full program must contain a `main` method. It only says:

> The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class, passing it a single argument, which is an array of strings.

So to the best of our efforts, we can define a Java program as something which when invoked in this way will provide an output:

```
$ javac A.java
$ java A
```

All the following templates do that.

#### Java 8 (42 bytes)

```
interface A{static void main(String[]a){/* Your code here */}}
```

#### Java 7 (45 bytes)

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){/* Your code here */}}
```

#### Java 5, 6 (12 or 27 bytes)

```
enum A{A;{/* Your code here */}}
```

This code above **will** write something on `stderr`. Usually something like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main\nException in thread "main"`. If you can write on `stderr` after execution, use this!

```
enum A{A;{/* Your code here */System.exit(0);}}
```

This code above is longer (27 bytes), but it **will** execute your code **and** avoid writing anything on `stderr`.

#### Conclusion

1. Don't ever use Java 7.
2. If your program can be written in Java 5 or 6, use it. If your program can be written in Java 5 or 6, but is longer than a Java 8 version, always check if it could be shorter to write it in Java 5 or 6.

Answer (score 6):

Using Java Applet can save you a lot of space:

```java
import java.applet.Applet;

public class B extends Applet{
    public B(){
        System.out.print("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Hello world!

Also this can be even more shorten by making `B` to extends nothing.

```java
public class B{
    public B(){
        System.out.print("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

How ever in additional to desired output we will also get exception:

**Output:**

> Hello world!
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: B cannot be cast to
>   java.applet.Applet
>   at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Also you can combine this with constructor block and save another 10 bytes like this:

```java
public class B{
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Same output with exception as above.

Comment: One could argue that in case of an applet the HTML page in which it is embedded should count too.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann  Html page is the output of the program, here we are talking about the source code

Comment: Did applets change so much since I used them 20 years ago? Back then, you had a HTML document with an `<applet class=...>...</applet>` in it, which, when opened in a web browser, would execute the applet. The result of your System.out could appear in a Java console, but not in the HTML page itself. (You could some APIs to execute Javascript in the browser, thereby changing the page, but that is not what you are showing here.)

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Well you said it, this is definitely not the intended way of using applets, but if it's sufficient for your program to print to stdin and it can ignore the stderr than you can use my suggestion. Obviously, it will not print anything to a web page.

Answer (score 6):

When you have a method that should return a `boolean` or `Boolean`, i.e.:

```java
// Return true if the (non-negative) input is dividable by 5
boolean c(int i){return i%5<1;}
```

You can change the `boolean`/`Boolean` return-type to `Object` to save 1 byte:

```java
Object c(int i){return i%5<1;}
```

---

In addition, as you may have noticed, you can use a `<1` check instead of `==0` to save a byte. Although that is more a general code-golf tip instead of Java-specific.
This is mostly used when the integer can't be negative, like checking for length:

```java
a.length<1
```

instead of

```java
a.length==0
```

Comment: Nice tip! You may want to add another example in the "if it can't be negative" section to illustrate it, since `c(-21)` returns `true` with the current one.

Comment: Clarified. Also, don't you mean `c(-20)` instead of `-21`? `-21 % 5 = 4` and `-20 % 5 = 0`.

Comment: No, I meant `-21`. `-21 % 5 != 4` in Java, which is my point. The divisible by five function *would* work correctly if modulus always returned non-negative, but it doesn't. See [this example snippet](http://ideone.com/CfWTGC).

Comment: @Geobits Ah, thanks for the example. I almost never use negative numbers with `%`, so I forgot Java returns the remainder instead of the modulus, hence the difference..

Answer (score 6):

## How to Draw in Java...

Here's the shortest possible GUI paint boiler-plate:

```
import java.awt.*;
static void main(String[]x){
    new Frame(){
        public void paint(Graphics g){
            // Draw your stuff here.
        }    
    }.show();
}
```

## Golfed for 111 Bytes:

```
import java.awt.*;static void main(String[]x){new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){/*CodeHere*/}}.show();}
```

Answer (score 5):

In most cases, your program will be single-threaded, i.e it'll have only one thread running. You can exploit this fact by `return`ing from the main method when you have to exit instantly.

```
static void main(String[]a){if(condition)return;}
```

Compare it to "properly" terminating the program:

```
static void main(String[]a){if(condition)System.exit(0);}
```

Or pointing to `null`:

```
static void main(String[]a){if(condition)throw null;}
```

Or dividing by 0:

```
static void main(String[]a){if(condition)int A=1/0;}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Using `...` (varags) as parameter

In some cases it's shorter to use a Java varargs as parameter instead of loose ones.
For example:

```java
// Example input/output: 5, 4, 3 -> 60000
int calculateVolumeInLiters(int width, int height, int depth){
  return width * height * depth * 1000;
}
```

Would be golfed by most to this:

```java
int c(int w,int h,int d){return w*h*d*1000;} // 44 bytes
```

But can be golfed an additional byte to this:

```java
int c(int...a){return a[0]*a[1]*a[2]*1000;}  // 43 bytes
```

Note that all three integers are only accessed once in the method itself. Since `int` is pretty short it is only beneficial if you use them each only once inside the method, and have three or more of them as parameter.

With longer parameters this is usually more useful though. For example, this was my original answer for [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95457/52210) (calculate occurances of input character in input string):

```java
// Example input/output: tttggloyoi, t -> 3

int c(String a,char b){return a.replaceAll("[^"+b+"]","").length();} // 68 bytes
```

And I was recommended to golf it to this:

```java
int c(String a,char b){return a.split(b+"").length-1;}               // 54 bytes
```

But I ended up golfing it to this using `...`:

```java
int c(String...a){return a[0].split(a[1]).length-1;}                 // 52 bytes
```

---

NOTE: If the question/challenge asks for a flexible input, the `...` can be shortened to `[]` of course. If the question/challenge specifically asks for, let's say, three `String` inputs and disallows an `String`-array containing three values, you can use `String...` instead of `String a,String b,String c`.

Comment: Can't you use a `String[]` instead of using varargs? (saves 1 more byte)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Hmm.. good point. But that mainly depends on how flexible the input is for the challenge. If any input format is allowed, than that would indeed be shorter. I'll add this to this tips, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, a single for-loop statement might be replaceable. Consider the following code:

```
int m(int x){int i=1;for(;x%++i==0;);return i;}
```

This is a simple for-loop which is a solution to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105412/44713).

Since we know that `i` will not be large enough to cause StackOverflow errors, we can replace the for-loop with recursion instead:

```
int m(int x,int i){return x%++i>0?i:m(x,i);}
```

We can simulate a loop by using a ternary operator in the return statement to cause recursion.

This reduction is rather specific, but I can imagine more situations where this would come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Java 8, then you can:

### Replace Lambda expressions with method references

Lambda expressions can be replaced with method references. Method reference has following form:

```
ClassName::methodName
```

so if you use one letter names for classes it's shorter then lambda. Here are the rules

```
lambda form                  |  reference method form
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p -> ClassName.methodName(p) |  ClassName::methodName
p -> new ClassName(p)        |  ClassName::new
p -> p.methodName()          |  ClassName::methodName // where ClassName is class of object p
(p, q) -> p.methodName(q)    |  ClassName::methodName // where ClassName is class of object p
```

Examples (respectivly):

```
lambda                       |  reference method
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
p -> System.out.println(p)   |  System.out::println
p -> new HashSet<>(p)        |  HashSet::new
p -> p.getName()             |  Beer::getName 
(p, q) -> p.compareTo(q)     |  String::compareTo
```

So, if ClassName is "C", then we have following length diffs:

```
lambda form                  |  reference method form | length diff
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
p->C.methodName(p)           |  C::methodName         | 5 bytes
p->new C(p)                  |  C::new                | 5 bytes
p->p.methodName()            |  C::methodName         | 4 bytes
(p,q)->p.methodName(q)       |  C::methodName         | 9 bytes
```

### Simplify lambda expressions

And here are some rules of simplifying lambda expressions.

General form of lambda expression is

```
(parameters) -> { statements;}  // (String a, String b) -> {return a.compareTo(b);}
```

When there is only one expresion, it can be simplified as follows (**`return` should me ommitted**):

```
(parameters) -> expression      // (String a, String b) -> a.compareTo(b)
```

When **type declaration can be ommited**, it can be simplified as follows:

```
(parameters) -> expression      // (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b)
```

When there is only one parameter and there is **no need to declare type**, it can be simplified as follows:

```
parameter -> expression         // (String s) -> System.out.printout(s)
                                // to
                                // s -> System.out.println(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use `String#isEmpty()`

To check if a String is empty, you could use either of these:

```
s.length()<1  // 12 bytes
s.equals("")  // 12 bytes
```

However, using `.isEmpty()` is one byte shorter:

```
s.isEmpty()   // 11 bytes
```

---

Note that for Lists it's still shorter to check the size instead of using `isEmpty()`:

```
l.size()<1    // 10 bytes
l.isEmpty()   // 11 bytes
```

Comment: I don't really know Java that well but can't you just use s==""

Comment: @JohanduToit In Java unfortunately not. `String` is an Object, and since Java is passed-by-reference, `s` and `""` doesn't point to the same reference, even if they have the same value. So `new String("test") == "test"` returns `false`, and `new String("test").equals("test")` returns `true`. String literals are an exception to this rule, so `"test" == "test"` will return `true`, because the compiler references to the same spot in the background. [Perhaps better explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1682559) or `.equals` in general [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16194428/1682559)

Comment: @JohanduToit You could do `s.intern()==""` to force Java to replace it with the equivalent object from the string pool, but that's 14 bytes, not really an improvement over the other methods.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen _[...] since Java is passed-by-reference [...]_ -- more importantly since Java does not allow operator overloading and defines equality as identity.

Comment: actually, interesting enough, you can use s=="" if you make s="' at first, see my fizz buzz java program for an example https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz/218270#218270  I love how my ide says that s=="" doesn't work, but I can run the program just fine

Answer (score 3):

## Bit twiddling actions

### Swap variables

You might want to swap `int` and `long` variables. The usual way is to have a temporary variable:

```
void swap(int a, int b) {
  int t=a;a=b;b=t;     //  16 bytes
  System.out.printf("a=%d, b=%d%n", a, b);
}
```

But you can shorten it like this:

```
void swap(int a, int b) {
  a^=b^(b=a);          // 11 bytes
  System.out.printf("a=%d, b=%d%n", a, b);
}
```

Even if you reuse a temporary variable, it's just shorter to write that code, no matter the length of each variable name.

Does work with `short` and `byte` but at the cost of casting.

### Swap the variables so that the min is in a specific variable and the max is in the other

You have `a` and `b` and you don't know which is greater. But you want `a` to contain the lowest and `b` to contain the greatest.

```
void swapMinMax(int a, int b) {
  a^=b<a?b^(b=a):0;            // 17 bytes
  System.out.printf("a=%d, b=%d%n", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you can use lambdas with iterators:

```java
// SUBOPTIMAL: Don't use lambdas here!
Iterator<A>i=a.iterator();for(A x:(Iterable<A>)()->i){if(x==y)break;}return i.hasNext()?i.next():null;
Iterator<A>i=a.iterator();for(;i.hasNext();){if(i.next()==y)break;}return i.hasNext()?i.next():null;
Iterator<A>i=a.iterator();while(i.hasNext()){if(i.next()==y)break;}return i.hasNext()?i.next():null;

// Lambdas save 11 bytes here!
Iterator<A>i=a.iterator();Iterable<A>j=()->i;for(A x:j){if(x==y)break;}for(A x:j){if(x==z)break;}return i.hasNext()?i.next():null;
Iterator<A>i=a.iterator();for(;i.hasNext();){if(i.next()==y)break;}for(;i.hasNext();){if(i.next()==z)break;}return i.hasNext()?i.next():null;
Iterator<A>i=a.iterator();while(i.hasNext()){if(i.next()==y)break;}while(i.hasNext()){if(i.next()==z)break;}return i.hasNext()?i.next():null;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use *Try it online* to share lambdas

If the solution can be writen in a lambda, [Try it online](https://tio.run/##nVVNbxoxEL33V4x86aIQRz3TIgH5PLSHpq3SVD14dw27ibHR2ouAKL@djr8WlgBJKiUSMDNvnp/fjB/YnJ2qGZcP@eN6nQmmNXxlpXz6AHB2BjfS8GrMMq7BFMwAqzjUmucwVhUINk1zpmHKlqCkWEKmpMFaYKBLOREcptwUKqcfEKyMSDCw2ABzVebAkk7P9vmmEHpST7k0IBG64qauJOY9t2uHW7Vpcmsq7APaY4RvEaeLQAdxRh4nlGQvWXRj7BDCeQsh38/FqpQqU6B4fHNAJvMdWG2YKTMYoHJfIOmc9p9ul9rwKVW1oTOEMkImZAAD0uk99zYFQ0ixQO/P1@3cEWQBnIxgRBxNXajKOJauqScFPr5dew6576NPCJzv1upNaYhjrffP91pKlqITDHtED0nVVqFgunVLod0DmpIKJie0qefHhLmAiygM9hwpqbFFFXrGhroLaW2OtqxNKei4lpkplaQR57O/zD6MX9faXn09m4myab915C0G7C0EIlJDYBIv8Aqujl6gi0dClwHvpR7xCt7EJsIENnFA@lBsrHH9ijWuozU2c3TXmqNFnCPWDGDqJ@rGQIlMhVYwU1qXzlQK6c9xzdTClDOxGTHtBqs5zR0srHKsm6JIDHmQk3RXPh@MZGNSY@QD7bPC7ju/CD9qCj8KzMK/jAmBWzKrq2rpxLJS4@@4O8e1cB0zlfOJEmMb9j1SnjFMAHbaT5EKpfTZ1nyCdGm452ptVTDZ0LU577u1d9xsH5Yom2ezX7XA9JBoP7W7Svhl17WshdhMfxRzR5DTqEgjxvw1JbZk2LjqvuWqVeIYzDu9ti/uYYUHxA7kHu53rTvfmicX9sea1anA0oDgHqIpeiD49s9fe0Td8e0Zte@b@5jSNCFDGJLwfc8OySi@Q4fDOc0Tck5iBqdVLcO71WxJO8z2qXGh8Ppam/IFz2pUzsa8WR3GmLIs4zOTkEu4JB6r2Z4RK6SgxG9A3MN7Qifc2IO1lmNEd7H/wi0oQ6xlQq5JAG8WXUPdJbzO/FCLBV0k5I508f/IxSwjkd@ks/XxcMGKrhI7DZ3gx@f1@h8) can help you format and reduce what characters need to be included in the solution.

See [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149859/75506) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

### Convert number to string

It may seem obvious, you can shorten your code by adding the number to "":

```java
// int a = 123
Integer.toString(a) // 0
String.valueOf(a)   // -2 chars
"".valueOf(a)       // -6 chars
(""+a)              // -13 chars
```