# When does (x == x+2)?

Tags: math, arithmetic, c

The challenge: Define `x` in such a way that the expression `(x == x+2)` would evaluate to true.

I tagged the question with C, but answers in other languages are welcome, as long as they're creative or highlight an interesting aspect of the language.

I intend to accept a C solution, but other languages can get my vote.

1. Correct - works on standard-compliant implementations. Exception - assuming an implementation of the basic types, if it's a common implementation (e.g. assuming `int` is 32bit 2's complement) is OK.
2. Simple - should be small, use basic language features.
3. Interesting - it's subjective, I admit. I have some examples for what I consider interesting, but I don't want to give hints. **Update**: Avoiding the preprocessor is interesting.
4. Quick - The first good answer will be accepted.

After getting 60 answers (I never expected such prticipation), It may be good to summarize them.

The 60 answers divide into 7 groups, 3 of which can be implemented in C, the rest in other languages:

1. The C preprocessor. `#define x 2|0` was suggested, but there are many other possibilities.
2. Floating point. Large numbers, infinity <strike>or NaN</strike> all work.
3. Pointer arithmetic. A pointer to a huge struct causes adding 2 to wrap around.

   The rest don't work with C:
4. Operator overloading - A `+` that doesn't add or a `==` that always returns true.
5. Making `x` a function call (some languages allow it without the `x()` syntax). Then it can return something else each time.
6. A one-bit data type. Then `x == x+2 (mod 2)`.
7. Changing `2` - some language let you assign `0` to it.

Comment: Why the explicit hate for the preprocessor?  It's a legitimate part of the language, and in C's case, of the culture.

Comment: @JB, I don't hate the preprocessor. But it makes this specific question too easy. Without it, there's a challenge.

Comment: Why `4. Quick`? You mean "Whoever knows one and is lucky enough to read this question first"?

Comment: @Luc, Basically yes. I think it's more fair than "the answer I like best", and I saw no better way to choose between the correct answers.

Comment: @ugoren Let the community vote (and vote yourself for ones you like), then choose the top answer after 7 days or so :)

Comment: @Luc, I do let the community vote (and vote myself for ones I like). But as the question owner, I think I have the right to determine the accepted answer, regardless of the votes.

Comment: It should be pretty trivial to define a class with overloaded operators that would take care of this.

Comment: Regarding possibility 2: NaN _doesn't_ work. NaN+2 is again NaN, but NaN==NaN is false.

Comment: @MartinB, I guess you're right, fixed. You could make another question of it - when does `x != x`?

Comment: Shame... in old versions of Sage, you could just set 2=0

Comment: The Scala solution, where x is a Set containing '2', and + means `add to Set` by the standard library, without redefining `+` yourself, doesn't fit into these 7 categories, IMHO.

Comment: @userunknown, You're right, though I'd call it a sub-category of overloading. The main point is that `+` does something other than addition.

Comment: When Jon Skeet.

Comment: You can use bitfields like a one-bit data type, so actually it works with C

Comment: does javascript `x=NaN` work?

Comment: Why are this question and all the answers Community Wiki?

Comment: Could `x` be declared as `volatile int`, and its memory location mapped to some device that decrements it by 2 the first time it is read?  I guess this requires the C standard to specify a left-to-right order of evaluation for the operands of `==`. I don't recall if it does (but I suspect that it leaves the order unspecified).

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
main()
{
double x=1.0/0.0;
printf("%d",x==x+2);
}
```

Outputs 1.

Link: http://ideone.com/dL6A5

Comment: `float x=1./0` is a bit shorter and perhaps more elegant. But anyway, this surely is the first good answer.

Comment: Ahh good old divide by zero. That took me longer to figure out than I'd like to admit. haha

Comment: Argh, I also though of this, but on Windows is doesn't compile so I dropped it. :( +1 though

Comment: x=1e999 is another way of doing this.

Comment: @shiona `float x=1e20` would be enough

Answer (score 125):

Fortran IV:

```
2=0
```

After this every constant 2 in the program is zero. Trust me, I have done this (ok, 25 years ago)

Comment: All the more reason for me to never touch Fortran.

Comment: Does it at least throw a warning?

Comment: @MichaelStern WARNING: YOU ARE CHANGING THE VALUE OF 2!

Answer (score 100):

This seems to work:

```
#define x 2|0
```

Basically, the expression is expanded to `(2|0 == 2|(0+2))`. It is a good example of why one should use parentheses when defining macros.

Comment: Certainly works, and I think it's the most elegant preprocessor based solution. But I think doing it without the preprocesor is more interesting.

Comment: Is it just me or should `2|(0+2)` be `1`?

Comment: @phunehehe: `|` is [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR); `||` is logical OR.

Comment: Uh, I thought it was `/`, silly me :">

Comment: This somehow reminds me of little Bobby Tables.

Comment: can anybody tell me how does (2|0 == 2|0+2) become (2|0 == 2|(0+2)) ?

Comment: @rakeshNS: I added the extra set of parentheses to show [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). That's why I said "Basically".

Answer (score 79):

### Brainfuck

```
x
```

This does of course stretch "evaluate to true" a bit, because in Brainfuck nothing actually *evaluates* to anything – you only manipulate a tape. But if you now append your expression

```
x
(x == x+2)
```

the program is equivalent to

```
+
```

(because everything but `<>+-[],.` is a comment). Which does nothing but increment the value where we are now. The tape is initialised with all zeros, so we end up with a 1 on the cursor position, which means "true": if we now started a conditional section with `[]`, it would enter/loop.

Comment: +1 Must be the most creative bending of the rules.

Comment: Why do you need the `x`?

Comment: @James The question says to define `x` so here `x` is defined as `x`.

Comment: @James the answer doesn't `need` anything except the `+`

Answer (score 56):

## F#

```ml
let (==) _ _ = true
let x = 0
x == (x + 2) //true
```

Comment: I like this one. Instead of juggling numbers, simply redefine the meaning of ==

Comment: Hang on, isn't the equality operator in F# simply `=`? `==` isn't even defined by default.

Answer (score 50):

### C

```c
int main() { float x = 1e10; printf("%d\n", x == x + 2); }
```

Note: may not work if `FLT_EVAL_METHOD != 0` (see comments below).

Comment: +1 for real-world applications. Too many people don't understand floating point mathematics.

Comment: @mbomb007: I think they are different - the answer you link to relies on `INF + 2 == INF`, whereas my answer uses a single precision float which is large enough that 2 is less than one ULP.

Comment: @mbomb007: I also think they're very different - `∞ + 2 = ∞` is something anyone could understand and doesn't depend on anything computer specific, whereas adding 2 to a concrete number and it having no effect is a bit more surprising and specific to the limited precision of computers, and more interesting IMHO

Comment: This can readily fail when `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 1` as the math is done as `double`.  Recommend a larger FP value sure to exceed even `long double` precision like `1.0e37f`

Comment: @chux: thanks - I wasn't aware of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` - out of interest, do you know of any platforms/environments where it's set to something other than 0 ?

Comment: @PaulR `float x = 1e10; printf("%d %d\n", x == x + 2, FLT_EVAL_METHOD);` prints `0 2` on 64-bit PC "gcc version 5.4.0".  `x = 1e37f;` works there as hoped.

Comment: @chux: interesting - so are both `float_t` and `double_t` `typedef`'d to `long double` in that environment ? (*"all operations and constants evaluate in the range and precision of `long double`. Additionally, both `float_t` and `double_t` are equivalent to `long double`"*)

Comment: @PaulR Do not use `float_t` much.   C11 §7.12 2 confirms your [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/when-does-x-x2/7182?noredirect=1#comment290886_7182) and my `printf("%d %zu %zu\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD, sizeof (float_t), sizeof (long double));` --> `2 12 12`  LSNED

Comment: @chux: thanks for the confirmation - that's definitely something I may need to watch out for in future, as much of my code ends up being cross-platform.

Answer (score 36):

**C#**

```
class T {
  static int _x;
  static int X { get { return _x -= 2; } }

  static void Main() { Console.WriteLine(X == X + 2); }
}
```

Not a shortie, but somewhat elegant.

http://ideone.com/x56Ul

Comment: Dang it, just got a 'Nice Answer' badge for this post. Seriously, getting badges for EVIL stuff?! **Don't do this at home**!

Comment: It's evil, but it's so beautiful...

Answer (score 32):

**Scala:** `{ val x = Set(2); (x == x + 2) }`

---

**Haskell:** Define ℤ/2ℤ on `Bool`eans:

```
instance Num Bool where
    (+) = (/=)
    (-) = (+)
    (*) = (&&)
    negate = id
    abs    = id
    signum = id
    fromInteger = odd
```

then for any `x :: Bool` we'll have `x == x + 2`.

*Update:* Thanks for the ideas in comment, I updated the instance accordingly.

Comment: You can simplify: `fromInteger = odd`

Comment: Also `(+)` can be defined as `(/=)` I believe.

Comment: Shorter solution would be to make an instance for `()`.

Answer (score 31):

### Python

```
class X(int):__add__=lambda*y:0
x=X()

# Then (x == x+2) == True
```

Comment: Nice. All languages which support operator overloading can use similar solutions, but C isn't one of them.

Comment: Also works with overloading `__cmp__` as `class X(int):__cmp__=lambda*x:0` (or `__eq__` though slightly longer `class X(int):__eq__=lambda*x:True`

Comment: A couple characters shorter if you dont extend from int.. `class X:__add__=lambda s,o:s`

Comment: May I ask what that multiplication does?

Comment: @TheRare it's not actually multiplication. Because `__add__` is normally given multiple arguments (`lambda x,y:`), I save some characters by using * to pack all the arguments into a tuple (`lambda *y:`). See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) for more info.

Comment: Ah. I forgot that completely.

Answer (score 31):

**GNU C** supports structures with no members and size 0:

```
struct {} *x = 0;
```

Comment: Very nice! I thought about pointer arithmetic with very large data leading to wraparound, but didn't think of the opposite.

Answer (score 26):

PHP:

```
$x = true;
var_dump($x == $x+2);
```

Or:

```
var_dump(!($x==$x+2));
```

Output:

> bool(true)

Comment: I was actually trying to come up with this dead-simple PHP answer, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 25):

It's a common misconception that in C, whitespace doesn't matter. I can't imagine somebody hasn't come up with this in GNU C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CAT_IMPL(c, d) (c ## d)
#define CAT(c, d) CAT_IMPL(c, d)
#define x CAT(a, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    int a9 = 2, a10 = 0;
    printf("%d\n", x ==
        x + 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints `1`.

Comment: Nice, though perhaps not technically valid (`x == x+2` is still false). But once you bring up the idea, I think `#define x -2*__LINE__` is more elegant.

Comment: @ugoren thanks! If you want all this to be on one line, use __COUNTER__ instead of __LINE__ - requires GCC 4.3+ though.

Comment: `_CAT` is reserved identifier. Anything that starts with underscore, and uppercase letter is reserved in C.

Comment: @xfix that's exactly right, updated to remove UB.

Answer (score 20):

**C**

It's more interesting without using macros and without abusing infinity.

```
/////////////////////////////////////
// At the beginning                 /
// We assume truth!                 /

int truth = 1;
int x = 42;

/////////////////////////////////////
// Can the truth really be changed??/
truth = (x == x + 2);

/////////////////////////////////////
// The truth cannot be changed!     /
printf("%d",truth);
```

Try it if you don't believe it!

Comment: `0`. Nope, still don't believe it.

Comment: @MSalters: What compiler do you use? You might have trigraphs disabled.

Comment: VS2010. Quite possible that trigraphs are disabled by default. Either that or line concatenation doesn't work with `??\ `

Comment: MSalters: the trigraph `??\ ` is to be converted into a single `\ `, so there is no `??\ `. Some modern compilers however give warnings by default to both trigraphs and line concatenations even if enabled.

Answer (score 18):

### Mathematica:

```
x /: x + 2 := x
x == x + 2
```

I think this solution is novel because it uses *Mathematica's* concept of Up Values.

EDIT:

I am expanding my answer to explain what Up Values mean in *Mathematica*.

The first line essentially redefines addition for the symbol `x`. I could directly store such a definition in the global function that is associated with the `+` symbol, but such a redefinition would be hazardous because the redefinition may propagate unpredictably through *Mathematica's* built-in algorithms.

Instead, using the tag `x/:`, I associated the definition with the symbol `x`. Now whenever *Mathematica* sees the symbol `x`, it checks to see whether it is being operated on by the addition operator `+` in a pattern of the form `x + 2 + ___` where the symbol `___` means a possible null sequence of other symbols.

This redefinition is very specific and utilizes *Mathematica's* extensive pattern matching capabilities. For example, the expression `x+y+2` returns `x+y`, but the expression `x+3` returns `x+3`; because in the former case, the pattern could be matched, but in the latter case, the pattern could not be matched without additional simplification.

Comment: I think you should explain what it does. Most people don't know Mathematica (or what Up Values are).

Comment: Thank you @ugoren, I spend most of my time on the Mathematica Stack Exchange website, so I forgot to explain what made my example meaningful. I made an edit that explains the concept as concisely I could.

Answer (score 17):

Javascript:

```
var x = 99999999999999999;
alert(x == x+2);​
```

[Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/MYWjk/)

Comment: You could use `Infinity`, or `-Infinity`, and because of this you could use the shortcut of `x = 1/0`.

Comment: @zzzzBov: That's definitely a better code golf.  I chose `(99999999999999999 == 99999999999999999+2)` because I think it's a bit more interesting than `(Infinity == Infinity+2)`, though as the OP says, "it's subjective" :)

Comment: This is the only real-world case in which I saw a check like this for a good reason (besides programming riddles):  A (float-based) faculty-function was checking its input for being too great to be counted down by `-1` and recursing.  The language itself was Python, but that does not really matter in this case.

Comment: Smaller: `x="";alert(x==x+2)`. `==` in javascript always compares two strings as true.

Comment: @NicoBurns not ture :(

Comment: @NicoBurns, running that code in the console produces `false`; wherever you're getting that info on JS is wrong and should not be trusted.

Comment: I stand corrected. I did try this out in the chrome console to test it, but I must have done something wrong as I am also getting false now.

Comment: @NicoBurns You must have been caught by the fact most dynamic languages evaluate strings to true in an `if` statement (as in `if('string')...`), or some other kind of type juggling. But different strings are `!=` between each other.

Answer (score 17):

### **scheme**

```
(define == =)
(define (x a b c d) #t)
(x == x + 2)
;=> #t
```

Comment: Nice. Scheme's `(x == x + 2)` looks just like C's, but means a totally different thing.

Comment: Now do it for `(= x 2)`.

Comment: `(define (x a b c d) #t)` :)

Comment: @ugoren this is defined to do this by this program. x is simply a name of a function here. And so is ==

Answer (score 16):

Here is a solution for JavaScript that does not exploit the `Infinity` and `-Infinity` edge cases of floating-point addition. This works neither in Internet Explorer 8 and below nor in the opt-in ES5 strict mode. I would not call the `with` statement and getters particularly "advanced" features.

```
with ({ $: 0, get x() {return 2 * this.$--;} }) {
    console.log(x == x+2);
}
```

**Edited to add:** The above trick is also possible without using `with` and `get`, as noted by [Andy E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1793/andy-e) in [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript#4691) and also by [jncraton](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5385/jncraton) on this page:

```
var x = { $: 0, valueOf: function(){return 2 * x.$++;} };
console.log(x == x+2);
```

Comment: A nice concept - making `x` be a function call, although it looks like a variable read. I assumes left-to-right evaluation order, but it's OK since it's specified in JS (unlike C).

Answer (score 16):

Obvious answer:

## When this terminates:

```
while (x != x+2) { }
printf("Now");
```

Comment: +1 http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1070/8766 but this is actually ingenious.

Comment: I think `while(!(x == x+2)) {}` would be more in spirit

Comment: This answer predates that meta post with two years. Everything that is considered a cliche today was novel at some point.

Answer (score 14):

The following is not standards compliant **C**, but should work on just about any 64-bit platform:

```
int (*x)[0x2000000000000000];
```

Comment: Great in principle, but seems to be implemented wrong. `x` would be incremented in steps of 2^61, so `x + 8` would equal `x`.

Comment: @ugoren, it works for me, on Linux with 4-byte `int`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I missed the fact that it's an array of `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 10):

Sage:

```
x=Mod(0,2)
x==x+2
```

returns True

In general for GF(2**n) it's always true that x=x+2 for any x

This is not a bug or an issue with overflow or infinity, it's actually correct

Comment: Same trick works with PARI/GP

Answer (score 10):

### Common Lisp

```
* (defmacro x (&rest r) t)
X
* (x == x+2)
T
```

It's pretty easy when `x` doesn't have to be an actual value.

Answer (score 8):

### APL (Dyalog)

```
X←1e15
X=X+2
```

APL does not even have infinity, it's just that the floats aren't precise enough to tell the difference between `1.000.000.000.000.000` and `1.000.000.000.000.002`. This is, as far as I know, the only way to do this in APL.

Comment: I really like this because it's the first answer to exploit float precision.

Comment: @AndrewKS: Actually Paul R was a bit earlier.

Answer (score 8):

## Perl 6

I'm surprised to not see this solution before. Anyway, the solution is - what if `x` is `0` and `2` at once? `my \x` in this example declares sigilless variable - this question asks about `x`, not Perl-style `$x`. The `?? !!` is ternary operator.

```
$ perl6 -e 'my \x = 0|2; say x == x + 2 ?? "YES" !! "NO"'
YES
```

But...

```
$ perl6 -e 'my \x = 0|2; say x == x + 3 ?? "YES" !! "NO"'
NO
```

`x` is multiple values at once. `x` is equal to `0` and `2` at once. `x + 2` is equal to `2` and `4` at once. So, logically they're equal.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2.X (Using redefinition of (cached) integers)

I've noticed all of the python answers have defined classes that redefine the `+` operator. I'll answer with an even more low-level demonstration of python's flexibility. (This is a python2-specific snippet)

In python, integers are stored more or less this way in C:

```c
typedef struct {            // NOTE: Macros have been expanded
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
    long ob_ival;
} PyIntObject;
```

That is, a struct with a `size_t`, `void *`, and `long` object, in that order.
Once we use, and therefore cache an integer, we can use python's `ctypes` module to redefine that integer, so that not only does `x == x+2`, but `2 == 0`

```python
import ctypes
two = 2 # This will help us access the address of "2" so that we may change the value

# Recall that the object value is the third variable in the struct. Therefore,
# to change the value, we must offset the address we use by the "sizeof" a 
# size_t and a void pointer
offset = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_size_t) + ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp)

# Now we access the ob_ival by creating a C-int from the address of 
# our "two" variable, offset by our offset value.
# Note that id(variable) returns the address of the variable.
ob_ival = ctypes.c_int.from_address(id(two)+offset)

#Now we change the value at that address by changing the value of our int.
ob_ival.value = 0

# Now for the output
x = 1
print x == x+2
print 2 == 0
```

Prints

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 7):

### Perl

using a subroutine with side-effects on a package variable:

```
sub x () { $v -= 2 }
print "true!\n" if x == x + 2;
```

Output: `true!`

Comment: `sub x{}` "works" as well.. (at least in my 5.10.1), but i can't figure why..

Comment: Because `sub x{}` returns either undef or an empty list, both of which are a numeric zero. And x + 2 is parsed as x(+2). `perl -MO=Deparse` reveals `print "true\n" if x() == x(2);`

Comment: That's awesome, @mykhal and @Perleone!

Answer (score 7):

***Python***

exploiting floating point precision makes this very simple.

```
>>> x = 100000000000000000.0
>>> (x == x+2)
True
```

To make it less system specific requires an extra import

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = float(sys.maxint + 1)
>>> (x == x+2)
True
```

This should work in other languages too.
This works because the reprensentation of 100000000000000000.0 and 100000000000000002.0 are exactly the same for the machine, because of the way floating points are represented inside the machine.
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point for more information.

So this will basically work in any language that allows you to add integers to floats and have the result of this be a float.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution for C++ based on operator overloading. It relies on implicit conversion from an `enum` to an `int`.

```
#include <iostream>

enum X {};
bool operator==(X x, int y)
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (x == x+2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use `std::boolalpha` instead of `?:`.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a code challenge... but I golfed it. Sorry.

**Ruby - 13 characters - Infinity solution**

```
x=1e17;x==x+2
```

returns true

**Ruby - 41 characters - Op Overloading solutions**

```
class Fixnum;def + y;0 end end;x=0;x==x+2
```

or

```
class A;def self.+ y;A end end;x=A;x==x+2
```

Answer (score 5):

If it is ok to exploit the question a little bit, then I will add some new Java. The trick is for sure not new, but perhaps interesting that this is possible in Java.

```
static void pleaseDoNotDoThis() throws Exception {
    Field field = Boolean.class.getField("FALSE");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    pleaseDoNotDoThis();
    doit(1);
    doit("NO");
    doit(null);
    doit(Math.PI);
}

static void doit(long x) {
    System.out.format("(x == x + 2) = (%d == %d) = %s\n", x, x+2, (x == x + 2));
}

static void doit(String x) {
    System.out.format("(x == x + 2) = (%s == %s) = %s\n", x, x+2, (x == x + 2));
}

static void doit(double x) {
    System.out.format("(x == x + 2) = (%f == %f) = %s\n", x, x+2, (x == x + 2));
}
```

And the results:

```
(x == x + 2) = (1 == 3) = true
(x == x + 2) = (NO == NO2) = true
(x == x + 2) = (null == null2) = true
(x == x + 2) = (3,141593 == 5,141593) = true
(x == x + 2) = (Infinity == Infinity) = true
```

Answer (score 4):

This VBScript solution works similarly to my JavaScript solution. I did not use a preprocessor yet the solution seems trivial.

```
y = 0
Function x
x = y
y = -2
End Function

If x = x + 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "True"
Else
    WScript.Echo "False"
End If
```

Comment: I was going to post the very same solution in ruby, until I saw yours - it's possible because both languages permit omission of the parentheses.

Answer (score 4):

### Java

```
double x = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY; // Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY also works
System.out.println(x == x + 2);      // prints true
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the accepted answer at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7169/12205

Answer (score 4):

### Common Lisp

```
(let ((x   42)
      (x+2 42))
  (= x x+2))
;=> true
```

Answer (score 3):

**Ada**

```
procedure test() is
  type x_type is mod 2;
  var x: x_type := 0; -- 0 or 1
begin
  if x /= x + 2 then
    put('Error');
  else
    put('Equal!');
  end if;
end test;
```

This is similar to Sage. We use a 1 bit integer which is allowed to wrap. We could also use a floating point, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

### C#

I didn't see any rule stating x had to be a number:

```
class Program {
    public static Program operator +(Program x, int y) {
        return x;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var x = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine(x == x + 2);
    }
}
```

I defined `x` in such a way, but I also defined the `+` operator for the object stored in `x`.

http://ideone.com/ylNyM

Answer (score 3):

**JavaScript**

Here's a way do it without exploiting Infinity:

```
x = {
    value: 0,
    valueOf: function () {
        this.value += 2;
        return this.value;
    }
};

alert(x == x+2);
```

Answer (score 3):

## C

If you evaluate `x == x+2` directly you will get a false, but I think it is interesting because it makes usage of a different language feature.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  int bit:1;
} bitpack;

#define x a.bit
#define y b.bit

main() 
{
  bitpack a, b;
  y = x + 2;
  if (x==y) 
    printf("true\n");
  else 
    printf("false\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### C

let the computer find a value for `x`

```
int main()
{
  float x=0;
  while(x!=x+2)x+=2;
  printf("%f\n",x);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell

```
Prelude> instance Num Bool where (+) _ _ = True
Prelude> let x = True
Prelude> (x==x+2)
True
```

You could call that cheating but I assume that's what this is about :D

To make it work with more than just bool:

```
import Prelude hiding ((==),(+))
infixl 9 ==
(==) _ _ = True
(+) _ _ = True
```

Answer (score 3):

**[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/)**

```
gap> x:=[];
[  ]
gap> x=x+2;
true
```

Here x is an empty array.

```
gap> x:=Z(2);
Z(2)^0
gap> x=x+2;
true
```

Here x is a generator of GF(2).

```
gap> x:=Integers;
Integers
gap> x=x+2;
true
```

Here x is the set of integers.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (0 character)

According to the rule, it looks like I can suggest my 0 character definition of `x` in bash, since without any definition, I have:

```
if (x==x+2); then echo "true"; fi
```

Output

```
true
```

Is it fair?

Comment: You need the expression `x == x+2` to evaluate to true in some way. What you are doing is trying to output `true` regardless of the comparison result.

Comment: Your comment and downvote isn't totally fair; my piece of bash code is merely here for proving the test is true (because bash doesn't display 'true' by itself); if you replace the expression with something evaluating to false, the result will be different: `if false; then echo "true"; fi`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your code. What you actually do is define `x` to be `=x+2`, and the definition is always true (the rule allows this, since it shows an interesting aspect of the language). I mistakenly thought the `true` on its own is a command.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP

```
<?php
  $x = 1e17;
  echo $x==$x+2;
```

Works in many other languages as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Ruby**

```
def x;1.0/0;end
puts (x == x+2) #=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scala

```
case object x {
  def +(n:Int) = this
}
//defined module x

x == x + 2
//res0: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Java:

```
Float x = Float.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println(x == (x + 2));
```

It prints "true"

```
System.out.println(x);
```

prints 3.4028235E38

```
System.out.println(x+2);
```

prints 3.4028235E38

I think this is caused by the loss of precision.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, x must have a data type of just ONE BIT.

Since C99, there is the data type **_Bool** ; So this should probably work:

```
_Bool x;
x = 0;
if (x == x + 2) ...
```

Comment: shouldn't `x` be promoted to `int` in expresseon `x+2`?

Answer (score 2):

## Tcl, 22 chars.

```
proc (x args return\ 1
```

Comment: I don't know tcl but where is `x+2` here?

Comment: if you execute `(x == x+2)` after that, it will return 1.

Answer (score 2):

### J

```
x =: 1
```

There is no `==` operator in J, so`x==x+2` would actually mean `x=(=(x+2))`. Unary `=` is [an operator](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d000.htm), that will return `1` acting on any number, and as binary it is just an equality. So `1=(=(1+2))` => `1=(=3)` => `1=1` => `1`.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript

```
x=Math.log(0)
x==x+2
```

Prints

`True`

Answer (score 1):

### C#

Using infinity

```
Double x = Double.PositiveInfinity;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0}", x == x + 2));
```

Also works with

```
Double x = Double.NegativeInfinity
```

(this is actually the same as `1.0 / 0.0` approach)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

```
$isi = 1.0E+17;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 1e18;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 4.2E+20;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 9.2233720368548E+18;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 5.0E+19;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 6.0822444802213E+18;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 0x5468792130ABCDEF;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

---

```
$isi = 6082244480221302255;
var_dump($isi == $isi + 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python:**

```
>>> x=float('inf')
>>> x==x+2
True
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

```
f x = x == (x+2) where (==)=(<)
```

Always returns `True`, except when x is `1/0`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pascal

Here's a solution that takes a different approach (not the usual infinity trick).

```
Program xplus2;

Var value: integer;

Function x: integer;
Begin
   value := value-2;
   x := value;
End;

Begin
   If x=x+2 then
      Writeln('They are the same')
   else
      WriteLn('They are different');
End.
```

Works with 2+x too.

Comment: Nice idea but I don't the think the order of evaluation for your `x=x+2` expression is guaranteed, so whether this works or not will be compiler-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Python

```
>>> x=1e999
>>> x==x+2
True
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Haskell

```
f x = (x == x + 2)
    where x + 2 = x
```

Calling `f` with any argument (whose type is in the `Eq` typeclass) will evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Missing **GolfScript**?

`0:2;`
Then e.g. `15 2+` -> 15

Comment: Because in GS you can't write `x == x+2` with any sense... Nice idea though, does it redefine `2`?

Comment: @tomsmeding well the syntax is different, but you can write e.g. `x.2+=` and yes, basically it does "2=0".

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript

```
var x = Infinity;
```

So if you add anything to infinity it will remain infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to come up with something that doesn't fall under one of the existing seven groups is tough:

```
def x
  rand(1..3)
end

puts x==x+2
```

33% of the time, it's right all the time...

Comment: I get 100% of the time “TypeError: can't convert Range into Integer”. (At least with Ruby 1.9.2.) In case you correct the syntax to `rand 3` (that will result range 0..2, but should not matter for the result), you will get 11.11% correct answers. That is because you are comparing **2** random numbers and both have to take a certain value: the 1st number must be 0 and the 2nd 2. The 1st will be 0 in 33.33% of the tries, the 2nd will be 2 also in 33.33% of the tries. The 1st will be 0 **and** the 2nd will be 2 in 11.11% of the tries.

Comment: Ha, yeah I was joking about the statistic - I knew it would be calling rand twice. I was just grasping at straws for something 'different'. Kernel#rand accepts ranges in 1.9.3

Comment: Thanks for the version information. Didn't knew that.

Answer (score 1):

`$x == $х+2` for infinite pairs of numbers. Let's try it out.

## PHP

```
$х = 1;
$x = 3;

if ($x == $х+2)
    echo "LOL it works. Sort of black magic?";
```

Nah, it's not black magic. Truth is that one x is [Kha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kha_%28Cyrillic%29), that as Wikipedia states, `it looks the same as the Latin letter X, in both uppercase and lowercase, both roman and italic forms.`

There's actually no difference between them, so even if there are two different variables, rules are not broken, since I assumed that a x is a Kha.

Answer (score 1):

## SWI-Prolog

In query mode:

```
?- X = X+2, X == X+2.
X = X+2.
```

You just need to "assign" `X = X + 2`, then `X == X + 2` will be true. Why make things so complicated?

---

#### Real explanation

In Prolog, `x` is an *atom*, so it is not possible to make `x == x + 2` returns true. Variables in Prolog must start with an uppercase letter or underscore.

Therefore, my solution will define (uppercase) `X` so that `X == X+2`.

In Prolog, `==` compares 2 terms according to [standard order of terms](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare). Therefore, we only need to *unify* (`=` operator) `X` and `X+2` before doing the comparison.

Note that the unification `X = X+2` unifies `X` with the infinite term `X = (((...)+2)+2)+2`, much like how the unification `X = f(X)` unifies `X` with the infinite term `X = f(f(f(...)))`.

In Prolog, when a query succeeds, it will return `true` if there is no variable, or it will return the variable binding which satisfies the query. This explains the output `X = X+2`.

Answer (score 1):

## C

Defining x as `1==-2`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 1==-2

main()
{
  printf("%d", (x==x+2) ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scheme / Unicode**

```
(let
  ((２ 0) (x 9))
  (= x (+ x ２)))
```

I knew there had to be a Unicode character that looks like a 2 - and that there would be a language or interpreter lenient enough to accept it as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

## ECMAScript (also known as JavaScript):

```
x=1e17
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, denotational semantics

`x = undefined`

As most of you probably know, `undefined :: a` can be cast to any type - or in other words, every type contains a special value `undefined`, also called `⊥` (pronounced "bottom").
We say that `⊥` is *less defined* than any other inhabitant of that type, and while its a little too in-depth for this post, `⊥` can also be seen as a computation that never finishes.

Let's `import Data.Function`.

In there, there is a function called `fix`, which according to the Haskell docs finds the **least-defined** fixpoint of f, by repeatedly applying the function to itself. Let's recap:

We need to find a value `x`, for which `x = x + 2`, or, equivalently `x = (+2) x`. Lets factor `(+2)` into a function called `f`. We get `x = f x`, which is precisely the definition of a fixed point for the function `f`. Since we don't know `x` yet, we need a function that knows how to calculate a fixpoint, like `fix`; `x` is our placeholder for said fixpoint (`x = fix f`), so our whole equation becomes `fix f = f (fix f)`.

This is just the definition of `fix`, so `fix` indeed finds a fixed point for a given function!

What I'm trying to say is: To solve OP's problem, all we need to do is pipe `fix (+2)` through ghci. When we do that however, we see nothing, as ghci gets caught in an infinite loop. But since I said that infinite loops can be seen as ⊥, we arrive at the fact that `x = ⊥`, which by the way turns out to be the only solution to OP's question (who would have guessed).

Answer (score 0):

the answer is infinity or - infinity because infinity+2=infinity you can't find any other number that it's bigger than itself+ a number

Comment: Infinity is an answer, but not the only one (as you can see here).

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby**

```
1.9.3p125 :006 > x = Float::INFINITY  # or x = -Float::INFINITY
 => Infinity 
1.9.3p125 :007 > x == x +2
 => true 



1.9.3p125 :015 > x =Float::MAX
 => 1.7976931348623157e+308 
1.9.3p125 :016 > x == x +2
 => true
```

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, just override the "+" operator (really a function):

```
scala> class X { def +(a:Int)=this }
defined class X

scala> val x = new X
x: X = X@26e7127

scala> x == x+2
res3: Boolean = true

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Processing

```processing
float x=1e30;
print(x==x+2);
```

The output will be `true`

Not very creative, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

**Ruby**

That's surely cheating, but hey ...

```
#/usr/bin/env

class Fixnum
  def +(y)
    if self == 42
       self
    else
       self + y
    end
  end
end
```

Then for x being exactly 42 ... /me => [ ]

Answer (score 0):

## Python

```
>>> x=99999999999999999999999999999999999.
>>> x==x+2
True
```

Note the `.` at the end, which makes `x` a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

Most compact, correct that I could figure.

```
x=1/0;x==x+2
```

I also tried futzin around with toString() and clever output variance with casting, but while the results were correct sequentially, the == would never be true.

Answer (score 0):

### C++

I'm aware there have been a couple of similarly themed solutions, but here's mine nonetheless:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Plus {
  int x;
  Plus(int _x):x(_x){}
  Plus operator+(int _x) {
    return Plus(this->x + _x);
  }
  bool operator==(Plus _x) {
    return true;
  }
};

int main() {
  Plus x(0);
  std::cout << bool(x == x + 2); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python

I'm always looking for an excuse to use a class for golfing Python... alas, this isn't golf.

```
class foo:__add__=lambda a,b:a
x=foo()
```

Here, `x+2` is `x`, though `2+x` blows up with an error (I'd have to implement `__radd__`).  I could have hacked equality testing instead, but I'd still need to implement `__add__`.

Comment: `class foo(int):__cmp__=lambda*a:0` is easier

Comment: @gnibbler, I'd agree if addition didn't raise an exception.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? It doesn't raise an exception on 2.7.3

Comment: @gnibbler, ooh, I missed the (int).  sneaky sneaky.  don't know that I'd call it 'easier'.

Comment: well it's easier because you get to support `2+x` for free

Comment: @gnibbler, but I get out of defining a compare!

Answer (score 0):

### Python

Any language with floats - no need to go all the way to infinity

```
x=9e9**9
x==x+2
```

Answer (score 0):

## q/k

Pretty trivial using infinity (or null):

```
q)x:0w

x=x+2
1b
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python

```
class X():
 def __eq__(a,b):
  return True
 def __add__(a,b):
  return True
x = X()
print x==x+2
```

```
$ python x.py 
True
```

Answer (score 0):

### Sage

```
sage: print oo
+Infinity
sage: oo+2==oo
True
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy

```
Integer.metaClass.plus = { Integer y -> delegate }
def x = 0
assert x == x+2
```

The `plus` method is overridden to return the first number :-D

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC at least)

Using pointer arithmetic on an [struct of size 0](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Empty-Structures.html#Empty-Structures)

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {} empty;

main(){
    empty *x;
    printf("%d\n", x==x+2);
}
```

Comment: @han [already suggested exactly the same](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7204/3544).

Answer (score 0):

### Coffeescript, 18 chars

```
x=1/0;alert x==x+2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Lua](http://www.lua.org/), used in various products including World of Warcraft, Wireshark, Nmap, Adobe Photoshop Lightroom, and the Nspire line of Texas Instruments graphing calculators, supports operator overloading (using "metamethods") for tables (associative arrays). This code works in both Lua 5.1 and 5.2:

```
local x = setmetatable({}, {
  __add = function(a, b)
    return a
  end
})

print(x == x + 2) -- true
```

Answer (score 0):

### GolfScript

In Golfscript, you can redefine `+`, `2`, or `=` in order to make the statement true for any value of `x`!  Any of the following lines would suffice:

```
{;}:+; #Redefine + to ignore the second summand
0:2;; #Redefine 2 to be 0
{;;1}:=; #Redine = to always return true
```

Then:

```
10:x; #Any x would work
x x 2+ = #x==x+2
-> 1
```

If you want the answer in the exactly format of the question, we can do some other nonsense:

```
{0}:(:x:=:+:2; #redefine all the characters in the expression to 0
{];1}:); #redefine ) to pop everything off the stack and then return 1
```

So then:

```
(x == x+2)  #That doesn't look like GolfScript!
-> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Little know fact about Haskell is it doesn't always do divide by 0 errors.

```
let x=1/0 in x==x+2
```

This is because when you add 2 to infinity, it doesn't get bigger. It is weird that such a mathematical language would just deal with infinity so nonchalantly.

Answer (score 0):

## Rebol

Version of the Perl answer by *memowe*:

```
v: 0
x: does [v: v - 2]
```

With above defined you can now test in Rebol console...

```
>> x == (x + 2)
== true

>> equal? x x + 2
== true
```

And a Rebol version of *Joshua Taylor* Common Lisp answer:

```
x: 42
x+2: 42
```

In console...

```
>> x == x+2  
== true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy

```
x = Float.MAX_VALUE
assert x==x+2
```

Float.MAX_VALUE = 3.4028235E38
Float.MAX_VALUE + 2 = 3.4028234663852886E38
Which the == determines is close enough.

Answer (score 0):

## C++

Had some fun with operator overloading

```
#include <iostream>

class Tautology
{
  public:
    const Tautology& operator+(int n)
    {
        // Anything to make x + 2 compile
        return *this;
    }
    
    bool operator==(const Tautology& t)
    {
        // Any tautology equals any other
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
   Tautology x;
   std::cout << (x == x + 2 ? "true" : "false");
   
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++ / C-sharp

Here's another one depending on the definition of an infinite double according to the IEEE standard (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlf101a.doc%2Fxlfopg%2Ffpieee.htm).

```
int main()
{
   double x = 0x7FF0000000000000; // Positive infinity
   cout << (x == x + 2 ? "true" : "false");
   
   return 0;
}
```

In C# this could be written more readably as

```
 double x = double.PositiveInfinity;
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

Exploiting the big number / infinity approach as shortly as possible.

12 chars:

```
9e99==9e99+2 // true
```

10 chars

```
1/0==1/0+2 // true
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript

```
var x = {y: 0, toString: function() {return (this.y+=2)}};
console.log(x == x+2); // true
```

When you add number to an object you indirectly call `toString` method of this object. toString method returns number... Right side becomes number, then `==` operator converts `x` to primitive by using it's `toString` method.

Interesting article about related idea: [Fake operator overloading in JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/fake-operator-overloading.html).

Answer (score 0):

### Python (18)

```
>>> x=True;[x][x==2+x]
True
```

Gives True in interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

## J

```
   x=:!123
   x=x+2
1
```

This is also reliant on the floating point trick: `!123x=2+!123x` returns 0(`=` actually is the comparison operator, so no trickery there)

Or, maybe even better:

```
   x=:_
   x=x+2
1
```

simply sets x to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.7, 46 chars**

I see a lot of Python answers abusing real number limitations, I'm surprised no one's submitted this disgusting Python hack yet.

```
x=True;True=False;
if True is (x==x+2): print x
```

Returns:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

```
x=1/0;x==x+2
```

This doesn't work in strict mode, nor without a global variable (i.e `window`). Tested in `Firefox 38`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby

With some monkey patching, everything is possible.

```
class Fixnum
    def ==(obj)
        # Check if difference between self and obj is 0, -2 or +2
        "#{self-obj}"=~/0|\-?2/ ? true : false
    end
end
```

As I can't use `self==obj || self==obj+2 || self==obj-2`, as that would cause a StackError, I first transform them into Strings, then check if the difference matches `"0"`, `"-2"` or `"2"`

#### Test cases

```
# Make sure `x` is from type Fixnum
x=0

p (x==x+2) # => true
p (x+2==x) # => true
p (x==x)   # => true
p (x==x+1) # => false
p (x==x+3) # => false
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica

```
x=∞
```

Mathematica is perfectly happy to reason (within reason) with infinity, and knows that `∞` and `∞+2` are the same!

Answer (score 0):

## ForceLang

```
def x set y -2+y
io.write x=x+2
```

Answer (score -4):

```
 cout << bool(x == x+2);
```

! is not needed at all

Comment: It outputs `1`, which means `x == x+2` is false. I want `x == x+2` to be true.

Comment: yeah, sorry, fixed :D

Comment: I still don't get it. `x == x+2` is false in this case.

Comment: DevC++  says that it is true

Comment: I don't have DevC++ at hand, so could you please detail in the comments how/why that's possible?

Comment: It depends on the initialization of `x`, which isn't shown. So, no points for this answer.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
int x=5;
cout << bool(x == x+2);
}`
Works in DevC++. The reason is that the bool function is not looking for that expression to be true, it just looks if there an expression, if there is one, it is true, if no, it is false, imho

Comment: @bla2e, this means your solution is wrong. I want `x == x+2` to be true. Your code just checks that it exists.

Comment: The answer u set as best, is not even dealing with variables, `double x=1.0/0.0;`

Answer (score -4):

JavaScript

```
!!("x==x+2") // true
```

Comment: Can you really say this is *defining* x?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it was just a joke.