# Kolakoski-like self-referencing sequences

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, array

This is how the Kolakoski sequence (OEIS [A000002](https://oeis.org/A000002)) is defined:

> The Kolakoski sequence is a sequence that contains `1` and `2`, and the `n`th element of the sequence is the length of the `n`th group of equal elements (run) in the sequence itself. The first 20 terms of the sequence and the respective lengths are:
>
> ```
> 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1
> - --- --- - - --- - --- --- - --- --- -
> 1  2   2  1 1  2  1  2   2  1  2   2  1
> ```
>
> Essentially, the lengths of the groups of equal elements of the Kolakoski sequence is the Kolakoski sequence itself.

So far, so good, but that why should we restrict ourselves to `1` and `2`? We're not going to! Given two inputs, an array of positive integers `A` and an integer `N`, return the first `N` terms of the Kolakoski-like sequence defined by cycling through `A`. To get the grasp of it better, here is a worked example with the lengths of the newly added groups in brackets:

```
A = [2, 3, 1]
N = 25

2: [[2], 2 ]
3: [ 2 ,[2], 3 , 3 ]
1: [ 2 , 2 ,[3], 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 ]
2: [ 2 , 2 , 3 ,[3], 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 ]
3: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 ,[1], 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 ]
1: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 ,[1], 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 ]
2: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 ,[1], 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 ]
3: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 ,[2], 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 ]
1: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 ,[2], 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 ]
2: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 ,[2], 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 ]
3: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 ,[3], 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 ]
1: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 ,[1], 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 1 ]
2: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 ,[2], 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 2 ]
C: [ 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 2 ]
```

Here is another worked example with a leading `1`:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
N = 10

1: [[1]]
2: [ 1 ,[2], 2 ]
3: [ 1 , 2 ,[2], 3 , 3 ]
1: [ 1 , 2 , 2 ,[3], 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 ]
2: [ 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 ,[3], 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 2 ]
C: [ 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 2 ]
```

As you can see above, the final result was cut to `N = 10` elements. The `n`th element should be how long the `n`th equal-element group is, even if the element itself belongs in the group it refers to. As in the above case, the first `1` refers to the first such group which is just that `1`, and the first `2` refers to the second such group, which starts with it.

### Rules

- You may assume that `A` will never have two or more consecutive equal elements. `A` may contain an integer more than once, but the first and last elements will not be equal, and `A` will contain at least 2 elements (e.g. `[1, 2, 2, 3]`, `[2, 4, 3, 1, 2]` and `[3]` aren't going to be given). That's because if there were consecutive equal elements, the final result would've been an invalid prefix for such a sequence.
- You may assume `A` only contains positive integers (as such a sequence would be otherwise undefined).
- You may assume `N` is a non-negative integer (`N >= 0`).
- You can't return more terms than requested.
- Using any one of the [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061/41024) is strictly forbidden.
- You may use any [reasonable I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/41024).
- Your answer doesn't have to work beyond natural language limits, but [in theory your algorithm should work for arbitrarily large inputs and integers](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/41024).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

### Test cases

```
[5, 1, 2], 0 -> []
[2, 3, 1], 25 -> [2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 3], 10 -> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2], 20 -> [1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 3], 20 -> [1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3]
[2, 3], 50 -> [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[7, 4], 99 -> [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3], 5 -> [1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
[2, 1, 3, 1], 2 -> [2, 2]
[1, 3, 5], 2 -> [1, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 4], 10 -> [2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13856/41024) (2k+ users)

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8369/8478)

Comment: @MartinEnder thought I linked that already

Answer (score 9):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
Ṡωȯ↑⁰`Ṙ¢
```

Takes first the length, then the list.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vcGhJVX5x3aOmxsyiQ9v@P9y54HznifWP2iY@atyQ8HDnjEOL/v//b8BlZMplZABCpgZclpZcQB4QGhr8jzbVMdQxiuWKNtIx1jEE0hCeoY4xRAxImuuYQMShYoZwlcY6plCdRkA1AA)

### Explanation

```
Ṡωȯ↑⁰`Ṙ¢  Inputs: n=9 and x=[2,1,3]
Ṡωȯ       Apply the following function to x until a fixed point is reached:
           Argument is a list, say y=[2,2,1,3,3,3]
       ¢   Cycle x: [2,1,3,2,1,3..
     `Ṙ    Replicate to lengths in y: [2,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3]
   ↑⁰      Take first n elements: [2,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,1]
          Final result is [2,2,1,1,3,2,1,1,1], print implicitly.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
u<s*V]M*QlGGvz
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3Cs%2AV%5DM%2AQlGGvz&input=%5B1%2C%202%5D%0A20&test_suite_input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debug=0&input_size=3) or [Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qE%0Au%3Cs%2aV%5DM%2aQlGGvz&input=%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B5%2C+1%2C+2%5D%0A0%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B2%2C+3%2C+1%5D%0A25%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A10%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%5D%0A20%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+3%5D%0A20%0A%5B1%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+3%2C+1%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+3%5D%0A%5B2%2C+3%5D%0A50%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B7%2C+4%5D%0A99%0A%5B7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+7%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A5%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B2%2C+1%2C+3%2C+1%5D%0A2%0A%5B2%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+3%2C+5%5D%0A2%0A%5B1%2C+3%5D%0A%5B2%2C+3%2C+2%2C+4%5D%0A10%0A%5B2%2C+2%2C+3%2C+3%2C+2%2C+2%2C+2%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D&debug=0&input_size=3)

#### Explanation:

```
u                 start with G = input array
       *QlG       repeat input array
     ]M           put every element into its own list
   *V      G      repeat every list vectorized by the counts in G
  s               flatten
 <          vz    take the first (second input line) numbers
                  and assign them to G until you reach fixed point
```

Comment: Interesting alternative: `u&VSvzs*V]M*Ql`

Comment: This is a nice approach.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>120</s> <s>114</s> 108 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to plannapus*

```r
function(A,N){i=inverse.rle
w=length
a=rle(A)
while(w(a$l)<N){a[[1]]=i(a)
a[[2]]=rep(A,l=w(a$l))}
i(a)[0:N]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBDsIgFET3nMKFi/8TNIAaU1MWvUAvQFiQBiwJoQarLEzPjjRd6O69mcmk4nbtobhXHGY/Rehojx8vfXzb9LTHFCzJMth4n0diZFXokOTRV8hg9gHbujdKca2lB4Oksqic7KN@BbmNcCFrqdit10txMICgJ8qRiguSP2WbXekZadP8KrEGnGH5Ag)

Anonymous function; successively inverts the RLE, replacing the lengths `a[[1]]` with the inverted RLE, and the values `a[[2]]` with `A` replicated to a length equal to that of `a$l`.

Comment: @plannapus ah, right! I did try that and crashed R because in assignment, it'll create `a$l` and `a$v` if they don't exist, but they won't affect the call to `inverse.rle`, causing an infinite loop. I think I can only use `a$l` in the `while` condition and the `rep` condition.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>151 + 19</s> <s>119</s> 115 bytes

```
a->n->{int c=0,l[]=new int[n],i=0,j;for(;i<n;i++)for(j=0;j<(c==i?a[i]:l[i])&c<n;j++)l[c++]=a[i%a.length];return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/LTsMwELznK1aVQDFxrfI41XG4IXHg1GPkg3HdsMZ1Iscpqqp8e3CqAAfmsNLOzGpnrDqpddsZb/efEx67NkSwiWNDRMcOg9cRW8/uePZPTFzWDe8ONWin@h7eFHq4ZJDQRxUT/7Lcl@hjLenf/uqjaUygcBWqChoQMKl15dfVJXGgxYa6Wgpvvq4eLykmyvJDG3KOpedYFGRerNhwW@ZaCHxWNcqtS4Pc6mSxyeJqXRRSJOVGMWd8Ez8kDyYOwYPj45RKzIGXIkvuU4t7OKY6@S4G9E0tQYWmJ0u7GfPrOShuG6a6zp3zn6jy8kDhkUKaTyNZxPsNIb@3M3bnPpoja4fIuvQi5lis6Irwq2nMxukb)

Comment: You can reduce four bytes by getting rid of two parenthesis, changing `&&` to `&` and removing a comma: `a->n->{int c=0,l[]=new int[n],i=0,j;for(;i<n;i++)for(j=0;j<(c==i?a[i]:l[i])&c<n;j++)l[c++]=a[i%a.length];return l;}` (**115 bytes**)

Comment: Suggest `(c==i?a:l)[i]` instead of `c==i?a[i]:l[i]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 68 bytes

Many thanks to Laikoni and flawr for their help in debugging and golfing this answer in the PPCG Haskell chatroom, [Of Monads and Men](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men). Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmvoaxpG/NfQy9NU68kMTuVK00h0UGjyipe01ajykYl2lBPrypWU1s7JV8h00YXxI21Tq5MzklVSFRUzIQoSAOzY//nJmbmKdgqFBRl5pUoqCgYmSpHG@kY6xjG/v@XnJaTmF78Xze5oAAA)

```hs
(.f).take
f a@(z:_)=(z<$[1..z])++do i<-[1..];cycle a!!i<$[1..f a!!i]
```

The first line is an anonymous function. The second line is the infinite list comprehension that produces our Kolakoski-like sequence.

**Explanation**

First, we define `z` as the head of `a` with `a@(z:_)`. Then, we initialize the sequence with `(z<$[1..z])`.

Then, from `1` onwards, `do i<-[1..]`, we append the following to the sequence: `cycle a!!i<$[1..f a!!i]`, which is the `i`-th member of `a` (cycled indefinitely) appended `f a!!i` times.

Finally, the anonymous function simply takes the first `n` terms of our Kolaskoski-like sequence.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 123 bytes

```python
x,y=input()
k=x[0]
t,j=[],0
if k==1:t,j=[k]+x[1]*[x[1]],2
while len(t)<y:t+=(j and t[j]or k)*[x[j%len(x)]];j+=1
print t[:y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsMgEETP4Sv2UmHXHIDUikLKlyAOkUNqcIQtiyjw9S6YSO0Fzcy@2WVJYZw934b5ZiTGeIskSeuXZ2haNMmoqEaBOKk0ocjeYZKSiT2YdBcV05@qvJpw9Brtw8DD@Ca030mETjYOrv4GQTk9rzC1hXUfhYit1hfXSYaW1fqQEZH0lu@jeyYtWA/r1f@YhrFWoENYkzDRDFC@iQ4mDmYJYq/iMD7xpnoCjADXBChSnMAx@2x4j1TJc5Ado9WVQZXHt3wDfZYnAl9Zns//m/2OsL@9tZ0H1dSLvFYZ/QU)