# Magrathea 2.0 - Building Mountains

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

With the big crash of the universal economy also the demand for custom made planets plunged. The Magratheans had to look after more steady revenues also from a broader class of customers. Therefore, they invented the have-your-own chain of mountain (or short havoc-o-mountains) for people with smaller budget who could not afford a complete planet.

The mountains are build according to the customer's plan (a.k.a. strings of digits and dots) and delivered using ascii-art (consisting of  , `/`, `\`, `^` and `v`).

#### Task

Write a complete program which takes input (single string) either from STDIN or as argument and outputs to STDOUT. This puzzle is a code-golf so please show some attempt at golfing.

#### Input

A string of dots and digits providing the basis for the mountain chain. Each string is exactly as long as necessary to support the mountains and each peak is given by a digit instead of a dot, indicating the height of the peak.

#### Output

An ascii version of the mountain chain.

- Each digit in the input represents exactly one peak (`^`) at exactly the height indicated by the digit (i.e. 9 is the highest height).
- There must not be additional peaks in the output (i.e. at places where there is a dot in the input).
- Mountains are of triangular shape, i.e. slopes are created using `/` and `\` characters.
- Passes where two mountains overlap are shaped using the character `v`.
- No superfluous newlines nor blank lines.
- Padding lines with trailing spaces is optional.

You may assume that the input provided is valid, i.e. there always exists a solution according to the rules (e.g. an input of `13..` would not result in a valid configuration and may be ignored). Moreover, on each side there are exactly as many dots such that the mountains must no be cropped.

#### Examples

The first line shows the input, all other lines constitute the desired output. (Actually the mountains look much better in my console than here.)

```
1
^

11
^^

1.2.
  ^
^/ \

.2.3..
   ^
 ^/ \
/    \

.2..3..
    ^
 ^ / \
/ v   \

...4...3...3..
   ^
  / \  ^   ^ 
 /   \/ \ / \
/        v   \
```

Comment: What a combination of poetry and art!  I love it.

Comment: Is printing extra newlines okay? In other words, for an input of `1`, is `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n^` allowed?

Comment: @durron597 The output should have no superfluous newlines, have a look at the examples.

Comment: What about trailing space characters?  Is it OK if all lines are the same length as the original string, padded out with spaces?

Comment: @Chron Yes, that's OK.

Comment: Hmm, what would the result be for "..32."?  I suspect my code is handling this incorrectly, assuming it's a valid input.

Comment: Great question!
Note: running `$('pre').css({lineHeight:'1em'})` on the browser's console will make the mountains look less like Christmas trees :)

Answer (score 11):

### Javascript: <s>272</s> <s>268</s> <s>233</s> <s>232</s> <s>201</s> <s>192</s> <s>189</s> <s>188</s> <s>178</s> 180 characters

Thanks to @Sam for reducing it from 268 to 233 characters, and for @manatwork for another 1 char. @VadimR for pointing out a bug.

```javascript
p=prompt(r=t='');s=' ';for(d=10;d--;r=s+q+s,t+=q.trim()?q+'\n':'')for(q='',i=0;i<p.length;)q+=' \\/v^'[p[i++]==d?4:(/\^|\\/.test(r[i-1])+2*/\^|\//.test(r[i+1]))*(r[i]==s)];alert(t)
```

Properly idented and somewhat ungolfed version with comments:

```javascript
// The output initialization is just a golfing trick suggested by @manatwork.
input = prompt(state = output = '');
space = ' ';

// Repeat for each line, from the top (the highest peak, highest digit) to the floor (digit 1). Start at 10 to avoid a bug.
for (digit = 10; digit--;

      // Update the state of our automaton, at the end of the iteration.
      // Add a space after and before to simplify the future pattern recognization.
      state = space + line + space,

      // Add the line to the output if it is not an empty line, at the end of the iteration.
      output += line.trim() ? q + '\n' : '')
{ // This curly brace was added for readability, it is not in the golfed source.

  // Analyze each character in the current state to produce a new state, like a cellular automaton.
  for (line = '', i = 0; i < input.length;)
  { // This curly brace was added for readability, it is not in the golfed source.
    line +=

        // If the input is the current digit number, evaluate to 4 and put a peak in this character.
        // Otherwise evaluate this expression with those rules:
        // 1 means that the hill is higher only at right in the previous iteration, we do climb it to the right in this one.
        // 2 means that the hill is higher only at left in the previous iteration, we do climb it to the left in this one.
        // 3 means that the hill is higher at both sides in the previous iteration, we are in a v-shaped valley.
        // 0 means nothing to do here. If the middle is not a space, it will be multiplied by 0 and become 0.
        ' \\/v^'[input[i++] == digit ? 4 : (/\^|\\/.test(state[i - 1]) + 2 * /\^|\//.test(state[i + 1])) * (r[i] == space)];
    } // This curly brace was added for readability, it is not in the golfed source.
} // This curly brace was added for readability, it is not in the golfed source.

// Give the final output.
alert(output);
```

As you may note from the code, this works as a cellular automaton, where each cells checks for a number in the input, looks to itself and to its two neighbours to decide what the next iteration will be. At each moment a cell may be a `^`, `/`, `\`, `v` or . The input provided in the test cases produces the expected output.

Note that using the `alert` box sucks, since it normally does not have a monospaced font. You may copy & paste the text from the `alert` box to somewhere else for a better appreciation of the output, or you may replace the last line `alert` by `console.log`, but since this is code-golf, `alert` is shorter.

Further, it does not validates anything in the input. It simply considers unrecognized characters as spaces the same way it does to `.` (in fact `.` is an unrecognized character too).

Comment: There is an old golfing trick to reduce 1 character: [initialize variables with empty string as `prompt()`'s parameter](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2684).

Comment: Excuse me, maybe I'm missing something, but I'm getting consistent results in both FF and Chromium. I launch a browser, run JS code from revision#14, and get error message. Then I run code from revision#1 - it runs OK. Again I run 14's code - and no error message, it runs OK. So revision#14's code can not be run by itself?

Comment: @VadimR Thanks, fixed. That was a side-effect for testing it with a poluted environment. Needed to prefix the code with `delete r; delete s; delete q; delete p; delete t; delete i; delete d;` to ensure that it was not poluted.

Comment: `q.trim()?q+'\n':''` could be `q.trim()&&q+'\n'`, saving two. Also, `i<p.length` could just be `p[i]`.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby, <del>208</del> <del>201</del> 189

Very fun challenge!  Here's an alternative Ruby solution.

```ruby
gets.size.times{|x|0.upto(h=$_[x].to_i-1){|d|r=$*[h-d]||=' '*~/$/
[x+d,x-d].map{|o|r[o]=r[o]>?!??v:o<x ??/:?\\if r[o]<?w}
d<1?r[x]=?^:r[x-d+1,w=2*d-1]=?w*w}}
puts$*.reverse.*($/).tr(?w,' ')
```

As a bonus, here's a Ruby implementation of Victor's very clever "cellular automaton" algorithm, at 162 characters:

```ruby
s=gets
9.downto(1){|h|$0=(-1..s.size).map{|x|$_=$0[x,3]
s[x]=="#{h}"??^:~/  [\^\/]/??/:~/[\^\\]  /??\\:~/[\^\\] [\^\/]/??v:' '}*''
$*<<$0[1..-2]if$0=~/\S/}
puts$*
```

Example output:

```
....5.....6..6.....
          ^  ^
    ^    / \/ \
   / \  /      \
  /   \/        \
 /               \
/                 \
```

Comment: I think you may use `$/` for newline.

Answer (score 4):

C# - 588 characters - not as good as Ray's 321 though!

```
class P{static void Main(string[] a){char[,] w=new char[a[0].Length+1,10];int x=0;foreach(char c in a[0]){if(c!='.'){int h=int.Parse(c+"");if(w[x,h]=='\0')w[x,h]='^';int s=1;for(int l=h-1;l>0;l--){for(int m=x-s;m<=x+s;m++){if(w[m,l]!='\0'){if(w[m,l]=='^')w[m,l]='/';if(w[m,l]=='\\')w[m,l]='v';}else{if(m==x-s)w[m,l]='/';else if(m==x+s)w[m,l]='\\';else w[m,l]='\0';}bool t=false;for(int f=9;f>0;f--){if(t)w[m,f]='\0';if(w[m,f]!='\0')t=true;}}s++;}}x++;}for(int k=9;k>0;k--){string u="";for(int j=0;j<w.GetLength(0);j++){u+=w[j,k];}if(u.Replace("\0","")!="")System.Console.WriteLine(u);}}}
```

Example output:

```
F:\>mountains ".2..3..4..."
       ^
    ^ / \
 ^ / v   \
/ v       \
```

Or a longer more complex one...

```
F:\>mountains ".2..3..6.....5...3......1..3..4....2."
       ^
      / \    ^
     /   \  / \               ^
    /     \/   \ ^         ^ / \
 ^ /            v \       / v   \  ^
/ v                \    ^/       \/ \
```

Brilliant puzzle... not as easy as it seems... loved it!

Comment: "Complex one" is ill-formed, there's no peak for "3".

Comment: All the `3`s are there. If you're talking about the first one, it's part of the slope.

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 65 bytes

[`⍉⌽↑⌽¨h↑¨'^/v\'[1+(~×a)×2+×2+/2-/0,0,⍨h←¯1+⊃⌈/a-↓|∘.-⍨⍳⍴a←11|⎕d⍳⍞]`](http://tryapl.org/?a=s%u2190%27...4...3...3..%27%20%u22C4%20%u2349%u233D%u2191%u233D%A8h%u2191%A8%27%5E/v%5C%27%5B1+%28%7E%D7a%29%D72+%D72+/2-/0%2C0%2C%u2368h%u2190%AF1+%u2283%u2308/a-%u2193%7C%u2218.-%u2368%u2373%u2374a%u219011%7C%u2395d%u2373s%5D&run)

`⍞` this symbol returns raw (not evaluated) input as a character array.

Solving interactively, in an APL session:

```
      s←'...4...3...3..' ⍝ let's use s instead of ⍞
      ⎕d ⍝ the digits
0123456789
      ⎕d⍳s ⍝ the indices of s in ⎕d or 11-s if not found
11 11 11 5 11 11 11 4 11 11 11 4 11 11
      11|⎕d⍳s ⍝ modulo 11, so '.' is 0 instead of 11
0 0 0 5 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 4 0 0
      a←11|⎕d⍳s ⍝ remember it, we'll need it later
      ⍴a ⍝ length of a
14
      ⍳⍴a
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
      ⍝ ∘.-    subtraction table
      ⍝ ∘.-⍨A  same as: A ∘.- A
      ⍝ |      absolute value
      |∘.-⍨⍳⍴a
 0  1  2  3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
 1  0  1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8  9 10 11 12
 2  1  0  1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8  9 10 11
 ...
13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4  3  2  1  0
      ⍝ ↓      split the above matrix into rows
      ⍝ a-     elements of "a" minus corresponding rows
      ⍝ ⊃⌈/    max them together
      ⊃⌈/a-↓|∘.-⍨⍳⍴a
2 3 4 5 4 3 3 4 3 2 3 4 3 2
      ⍝ This describes the desired landscape,
      ⍝ except that it's a little too high.
      ⍝ Add -1 to correct it:
      ¯1+⊃⌈/a-↓|∘.-⍨⍳⍴a
1 2 3 4 3 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1
      ⍝ Perfect!  Call it "h":
      h←¯1+⊃⌈/a-↓|∘.-⍨⍳⍴a
      0,⍨h ⍝ append a 0 (same as h,0)
1 2 3 4 3 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 0
      0,0,⍨h ⍝ also prepend a 0
0 1 2 3 4 3 2 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 0
      2-/0,0,⍨h ⍝ differences of pairs of consecutive elements
¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 1 1 0 ¯1 1 1 ¯1 ¯1 1 1 1
      ⍝ this gives us slopes between elements
      2+/2-/0,0,⍨h ⍝ sum pairs: left slope + right slope
¯2 ¯2 ¯2 0 2 1 ¯1 0 2 0 ¯2 0 2 2
      ×2+/2-/0,0,⍨h ⍝ signum of that
¯1 ¯1 ¯1 0 1 1 ¯1 0 1 0 ¯1 0 1 1
      2+×2+/2-/0,0,⍨h ⍝ add 2 to make them suitable for indexing
1 1 1 2 3 3 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 3
      ⍝ Almost ready.  If at this point we replace
      ⍝ 1:/ 2:v 3:\, only the peaks will require fixing.
      ~×a ⍝ not signum of a
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
      (~×a)×2+×2+/2-/0,0,⍨h ⍝ replace peaks with 0-s
1 1 1 0 3 3 1 0 3 2 1 0 3 3
      ⍝ Now replace 0:^ 1:/ 2:v 3:\
      ⍝ We can do this by indexing a string with the vector above
      ⍝ (and adding 1 because of stupid 1-based indexing)
      '^/v\'[1+(~×a)×2+×2+/2-/0,0,⍨h]
///^\\/^\v/^\\
      ⍝ Looks like our mountain, only needs to be raised according to h
      r←'^/v\'[1+(~×a)×2+×2+/2-/0,0,⍨h] ⍝ name it for convenience
      h¨↑r ⍝ extend r[i] with spaces to make it h[i] long
 /  /   /    ^     \    \   /   ^    \   v  /   ^    \   \
      ↑⌽¨h¨↑r ⍝ reverse each and mix into a single matrix
/
 /
  /
   ^
  \
 \
 /
  ^
 \
v
 /
  ^
 \
\
      ⍉⌽↑⌽¨h¨↑r ⍝ reverse and transpose to the correct orientation
   ^
  / \  ^   ^
 /   \/ \ / \
/        v   \
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 390 characters

Whew, this one was tricky.

I ended up having to append to a new string for each character, using a variable `s` that meant "skip next character" which was needed for processing `^` and `\`.

This output exactly the given sample output for all of the test cases.

```
m=[gets.chomp]
a=m[0].scan(/\d/).max.to_i
m[0].gsub!(/./){|n|n==?. ? ' ':a-n.to_i}
s=nil
until a==0
o=''
m[-1].chars{|c|o+=case c
when ?0;?^
when ' ';t=s;s=nil;t ? '':' '
when /\d/;(c.to_i-1).to_s
when ?^;s=1;o.slice! -1;"/ \\"
when ?/;t=s;s=nil;t ? "#{o.slice! -1;' '}":o.slice!(-1)=='\\' ? 'v ':"/ "
when ?\\;s=1;' \\'
when ?v;' '
end}
m.push o
a-=1
end
puts (m[1..-1]*"\n").gsub /\d/,' '
```

Chart of what the variables mean:

```
m | The mountain array.
a | The highest height of a mountain. Used for counting when to stop.
s | Whether or not to skip the next character. 1 for yes, nil for no.
o | Temp string that will be appended to mountain.
t | Temp variable to hold the old value of s.
```

I'm sure I could golf it down *much* more, but I have to go now. Shall be improved later!

Comment: I'm struggling with the input `.2.2.` and can't see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <strike>377</strike> 407

**Edit:** @Victor pointed out that this needed to be a complete program, so I added a few dozen characters to make it compilable and runnable. Just pass the "purchase order" as the first param when executing the program, like so: `java M ..3.4..6..4.3..`

I think this is similar in spirit to other answers, basically just traverses the "mountain order" repeatedly for every possible height, and builds the mountains from the tops down. That way I only have to deal with four conditions if not building a peak -- either an up slope '/', down slope '\, joint 'v', or empty ' '. I can discover that simple by looking at the three spaces centered "above" my current position in my top-down build.

Note that like other submissions, I treat anything other than a number as equivalent to '.' in the input, for brevity.

Golfed version:

```
class M{public static void main(String[]m){char[]n=m[0].toCharArray();int e=n.length,h=9,x=-1,p;char[][]o=new char[11][e];char l,r,u;boolean a,b,c;for(;h>=0;h--){for(p=0;p<e;p++){if(n[p]-49==h){o[h][p]=94;if(x==-1)x=h;}else{l=(p>0)?o[h+1][p-1]:0;r=(p<e-1)?o[h+1][p+1]:0;u=o[h+1][p];a=l>91&&l<99;b=r==94||r==47;c=u<33;o[h][p]=(char)((a&&b)?'v':(c&&b)?47:(c&&a)?92:32);}}if(x>=h)System.out.println(o[h]);}}}
```

Human readable form (and without some of the equivalent transmogrifications to achieve golf form):

```
class Magrathea2 {
    public static void main(String[] mountain) {
        String out = "";
        char[][] output = new char[11][mountain[0].length()];
        int height = 9; int maxheight = -1;
        int position = 0;
        char left,right,up;
        char[] mount = mountain[0].toCharArray();
        for (; height >= 0; height--) {
            for (position=0; position < mount.length; position++) {
                if (mount[position]-49 == height) {
                    output[height][position] = '^';
                    if (maxheight==-1) {
                        maxheight=height;
                    }
                } else { // deal with non-numbers as '.'
                    left=(position>0)?output[height+1][position-1]:0;
                    right=(position<mount.length-1)?output[height+1][position+1]:0;
                    up=output[height+1][position];
                    if ((left=='^'||left=='\\')&&(right=='^'||right=='/')) {
                        output[height][position]='v';
                    } else if ((up==' '||up==0)&&(right=='/'||right=='^')) {
                        output[height][position]='/';
                    } else if ((up==' '||up==0)&&(left=='\\'||left=='^')) {
                        output[height][position]='\\';
                    } else {
                        output[height][position]=' ';
                    }
                }
            }
            if (maxheight >= height) {
                out+=new String(output[height]);
                if (height > 0) {
                    out+="\n";
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

Enjoy.

Example output:

```
$ java M ..3..4...6...5....1
         ^
        / \  ^
     ^ /   \/ \
  ^ / v        \
 / v            \
/                \^
```

Comment: The question mentions **Write a complete program**, so please, add the missing `class X{public static void main(String[]z){`.

Comment: Right on. I got misdirected by the next section of that sentence -- "or as argument" and missed the complete program part. I'll update it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6, <strike>264 224 216 206 200 194</strike> 124 bytes

```
$_=get;my$a=10;((s:g/$a/^/;s:g/\s\.\s/ v /;s:g'\.\s'/ ';s:g/\s\./ \\/;$!=say TR/.1..9/ /;tr'^\\/v' ')if .match(--$a)|$!)xx 9
```

Thanks to @JoKing for showing a s/// solution. This is golfed a bit further after fixing the tr/// bug in Perl 6.

My original solution with subst:

```
my$t=get;for 9...1 {if $t.match($_)|$! {$t=$t.subst($_,'^',:g).subst(' . ',' v ',:g).subst('. ','/ ',:g).subst(' .',' \\',:g);$!=say $t.subst(/<[\.\d]>/,' ',:g);$t.=subst(/<[^\\/v]>/,' ',:g)};}
```

Ungolfed:

```
my $t=slurp;
my $s;
for 9...1 {
    if $t.match($_)||$s {                    # match number or latched
        $t=$t.subst($_,'^',:g)               # peaks
        .subst(' . ',' v ',:g)               # troughs
        .subst('. ','/ ',:g)                 # up slope
        .subst(' .',' \\',:g);               # down slope
        $s=say $t.subst(/<[\.\d]>/,' ',:g);  # clean, display, latch
        $t=$t.subst(/<[^\\/v]>/,' ',:g)      # wipe for next line
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...4...3...33..4..4....2.3.22.33.5..22...333.222.3..
                                 ^                  
   ^           ^  ^             / \                 
  / \  ^   ^^ / \/ \     ^    ^^   \     ^^^     ^  
 /   \/ \ /  v      \  ^/ \^^/      ^^  /   \^^^/ \ 
/        v           \/               \/           \
```

Comment: I don't think Perl strictly needs a main function, the entry point can just be the first thing outside a function.

Comment: I used main for parameter handling. Now using stdin. Thanks.

Comment: A procedural solution. I'm sure someone can do better with regexes and hyperops.

Comment: [131 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYpRC4IwFIX/yhUGcw/em7MCW/YjoreWMUItSIgmotB/X7sGPRz4znfOq3k/tyGIa9U1g@ln4ap8ZdLU7zoSjmoyTNZbtJ5ghKVLbpJA/kcCa8mIpPJuhtORMEcsD/S70/5cx3m8sFCPFrB3w@2eZplw6iMSNU1QmhAQcR1TcIqFuaKORmtWG2TglQ17/AI) using `s///` and `tr///`. I think that last one can use `tr` instead of `s` but I can't quite figure out to translate backslashes. Maybe the first one too

Comment: Nice work @JoKing – I got into a topic mess when I tried to use s/// and TR///. I see that avoiding blocks is the answer.

Comment: 125 bytes with the tr/// bug fixed. Also spurious `>` removed from `TR/.1..9//`
`$_=get;my$a=10;((s:g/$a/^/;s:g/\s\.\s/ v /;s:g'\.\s'/ ';s:g/\s\./ \\/;$!=say TR/.1..9/ /;tr'^\\/v' ')if .match(--$a)|$!)xx 9`

Comment: Nice! If you've got a shorter code, you should update the answer with the new program.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - <s>321</s> 319

```
using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[]p){int h=p[0].Max()-48,i=h,j,n=p[0].Length;char[]A=new char[n+2],B=A;for(;i-->0;){for(j=0;j++<n;){var r=(A[j+1]==47|A[j+1]==94);B[j]=(char)(p[0][j-1]==i+49?94:i+1<h?A[j]==0?(A[j-1]>90&A[j-1]<95)?r?118:92:r?47:0:0:0);}A=(char[])B.Clone();System.Console.WriteLine(B);}}}
```

Ungolfed and commented:

```
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main(string[] p)
    {
        int h = p[0].Max() - 48,    // Getting the height. Codes for 0 to 9 are 48 to 57, so subtract 48 and hope no one will input anything but dots and numbers.
            i = h,
            j,                      // Declaring some iterators here, saves a few chars in loops.
            n = p[0].Length;
        char[] A = new char[n+2],   // Creating an array of char with 2 extra members so as not to check for "index out of bounds" exceptions
               B = A;               // B is referencing the same array as A at this point. A is previous row, B is the next one.
        for (;i-->0;)               // Looping from top to the bottom of the mountain
        {
            for (j = 0; j++ < n;)   // Looping from left to right.
            {
                var r = (A[j + 1] == 47 | A[j + 1] == 94);  // This bool is used twice, so it saves a few characters to make it a variable

                // Here's the logic
                B[j] = (char)(p[0][j - 1] == i + 49 ? 94    // If at this position in the string we have a number, output "^"
                                           : i + 1 < h ?    // And if not, check if we're on the top of the mountain
                                             A[j] == 0 ?    // If we're not at the top, check if the symbol above is a space (0, actually)
                                            (A[j - 1] > 90 & A[j - 1] < 95) ?   // If there's nothing above, we check to see what's to the left ( ^ or \ )
                                             r ?            // And then what's to the right ( ^ or / )
                                             118            // If there are appropriate symbols in both locations, print "v"
                                           : 92             // If there's only a symbol to the left, print "\"
                                           : r              // Otherwise check if there's a symbol to the right, but not to the left
                                           ? 47             // And if there is, print "/"
                                           : 0 : 0 : 0);    // Print nothing if there aren't any symbols above, to the left and to the right,
                                                            // or there's a "^" right above, or we're at the top of the mountain
            }
            A=(char[])B.Clone();    // Clone arrays to iterate over the next line
            System.Console.WriteLine(B);
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
C:\>program .2..3..4...
        ^
     ^ / \
  ^ / v   \
 / v       \
```

I think it outputs an extra space before each line, though.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>254 218</s> 212

```
$s=<>;sub f{9-$i-$_[0]?$":pop}for$i(0..8){$h=1;$_=$s;s!(\.*)(\d?)!$D=($w=length$1)+$h-($2||1);join'',(map{($x=$_-int$D/2)<0?f--$h,'\\':$x?f++$h,'/':$D%2?f--$h,v:f$h,'/'}0..$w-1),$2?f$h=$2,'^':''!ge;print if/\S/}
```

```perl
$s=<>;
sub f{9-$i-$_[0]?$":pop}
for$i(0..8){
    $h=1;
    $_=$s;
    s!(\.*)(\d?)!
        $D=($w=length$1)+$h-($2||1);
        join'',(map{
            ($x=$_-int$D/2)<0
                ?f--$h,'\\'
                :$x
                    ?f++$h,'/'
                    :$D%2
                        ?f--$h,v
                        :f$h,'/'
        }0..$w-1),$2
            ?f$h=$2,'^'
            :''
    !ge;
    print if/\S/
}
```

**Edit:** actually it's a bug-fix to work with ProgrammerDan's `..3..4...6...5....1` example, but, in the process, some bytes were off. And online test: https://ideone.com/P4XpMU

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, <s>128</s> <s>117</s> <s>112</s> <s>106</s> 104 bytes

CJam is a bit younger than this challenge so this answer does not compete. This was a very nice challenge though! From the little I know about J and APL, I think a submission in those would be impressively short.

```
WlW++"."Waer{_{~U(e>:U}%\W%}2*;W%]z{$W=}%_$W=S*\:L,2-,\f{\_)L=(~"^/ ^^/ \v ^ \\"S/2/@L>3<_$0=f-{=}/t}zN*
```

Here is a test case, which I think contains all possible possible combinations of slopes, peaks and troughs:

```
...4...3...33..4..4....2.3.22.33.5..22...333.222.3..
```

which yields

```
                                 ^                  
   ^           ^  ^             / \                 
  / \  ^   ^^ / \/ \     ^    ^/   \     ^^^     ^  
 /   \/ \ /  v      \  ^/ \^^/      \^  /   \^^^/ \ 
/        v           \/               \/           \
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

I'll add an explanation for the code later.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <del>297</del> <del>234</del> 218

-63 bytes thanks to Jo King
-16 bytes with `r=s.replace` instead of lambda

```python
s=input()
r=s.replace
q=0
j=''.join
for i in range(9):
 if`9-i`in s or q:q=s=r(`9-i`,'^');s=r(' . ',' v ');s=r('. ','/ ');s=r(' .',' \\');print j([x,' '][x in'0123456789.']for x in s);s=j([x,' '][x in'/\^v']for x in s)
```

Takes input from STDIN.
Ungolfed, simplified:

```python
s=input() # Take input
r=lambda y,z: s.replace(y,z) # Function for quick s.replace(a, b)
j=lambda x: ''.join(x)
q=0 # Acts like boolean
for i in range(9): # Count to 9
 if `9-i`in s or q: # When digit has been found or found previously (no newlines at start)
  q=s=r(`9-i`,'^') # Digit to ^, set q to non-zero value for always executing from now on
  s=r(' . ',' v ') # ' . ' to ' v '
  s=r('. ','/ ') # '. ' to '/ '
  s=r(' .',' k') # ' .' to 'k'. K is a placeholder, since \\ takes two chars and `[...]`[2::5] fails
  print j([x,' '][x in'0123456789.']for x in s) # Print without '0123456789.'
  s=j([x,' '][x in'/\^v']for x in s) # Wipe (delete '/^\v`)
```

Comment: [234 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7RbsIwDEXf8xUWL06lzkBK2VqUL6EgulFYKkjbpCDYz3dxJYTgwZLPubbs9t7/NlYNg9fGtpdeRsLpU3n@3pdwj/9yT65qT@VPJQNFotMzUWtEqhtjxaFxYMBYcKU9VjKLcgHmsMs@zC5IDyHu8k577eQoY9xitGJEIMAY4QoPMfIUnjnHRRG4dcb2UMv1LRjcrG/hIs7mKlmky8@vjHDDf7AFz9tvk9Nie30ZGYYJES1CJVzJ2DOSCkYpVilxwykb9jT5Bw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Yeah, I tried the `s.replace` method myself, but it doesn't work. You're just performing replacements on the original string since strings are immutable

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <s>148</s> 145 bytes

It's a nice challenge!

```powershell
param($s)9..1|?{($p+=$s-match$_)}|%{"$_,^; \. , v ;\. ,/ ; \., \;\^|\\|/|v, "-split';'|%{$x=$s-replace'\.|\d',' '
$s=$s-replace($_-split',')}
$x}
```

Less golfed test script:

```powershell
$f = {

param($s)
9..1|?{($p+=$s-match$_)}|%{      # loop digits form 9 downto 1, execute to the end as soon as a suitable digit met
    $s=$s-replace$_,'^'          # replace current digit with '^'
    $s=$s-replace' \. ',' v '    # replace ' . '  with ' v '
    $s=$s-replace'\. ','/ '      # replace '. ' with '/ '
    $s=$s-replace' \.',' \'      # replace ' .' with ' \'
       $s-replace'\.|\d',' '     # replace all dots and digits with ' ' and push to output. Don't store this replacement
    $s=$s-replace'\^|\\|/|v',' ' # prepeare to the next step: replace ^ \ / and v to space
}

    # Example:
    #     $s="...4...3...3.."
    # 4 : $s="...^...3...3.." output: "   ^          "
    # 4 : $s="... ...3...3.."
    # 3 : $s="../ \..^...^.." output: "  / \  ^   ^  "
    # 3 : $s="..   .. ... .."
    # 2 : $s="./   \/ \./ \." output: " /   \/ \ / \ "
    # 2 : $s=".        .   ."
    # 1 : $s="/        v   \" output: "/        v   \"
    # 1 : $s="              "

}

@(
    ,("1",
      "^")

    ,("11",
      "^^")

    ,("1.2.",
    "  ^ ",
    "^/ \")

    ,(".2.3..",
      "   ^  ",
      " ^/ \ ",
      "/    \")

    ,(".2..3..",
      "    ^  ",
      " ^ / \ ",
      "/ v   \")

    ,("...4...3...3..",
      "   ^          ",
      "  / \  ^   ^  ",
      " /   \/ \ / \ ",
      "/        v   \")

    ,("...4...3...33..4..4....2.3.22.3..5...22...333.222.3..",
      "                                 ^                   ",
      "   ^           ^  ^             / \                  ",
      "  / \  ^   ^^ / \/ \     ^    ^/   \      ^^^     ^  ",
      " /   \/ \ /  v      \  ^/ \^^/      \^^  /   \^^^/ \ ",
      "/        v           \/                \/           \")

    ,(".2..3..6.....5...3......1..3..4....2.",
      "       ^                             ",
      "      / \    ^                       ",
      "     /   \  / \               ^      ",
      "    ^     \/   \ ^         ^ / \     ",
      " ^ /            v \       / v   \  ^ ",
      "/ v                \    ^/       \/ \")
) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$result"-eq"$expected"
    $s
    $result
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True
1
^
True
11
^^
True
1.2.
  ^
^/ \
True
.2.3..
   ^
 ^/ \
/    \
True
.2..3..
    ^
 ^ / \
/ v   \
True
...4...3...3..
   ^
  / \  ^   ^
 /   \/ \ / \
/        v   \
True
...4...3...33..4..4....2.3.22.3..5...22...333.222.3..
                                 ^
   ^           ^  ^             / \
  / \  ^   ^^ / \/ \     ^    ^/   \      ^^^     ^
 /   \/ \ /  v      \  ^/ \^^/      \^^  /   \^^^/ \
/        v           \/                \/           \
True
.2..3..6.....5...3......1..3..4....2.
       ^
      / \    ^
     /   \  / \               ^
    ^     \/   \ ^         ^ / \
 ^ /            v \       / v   \  ^
/ v                \    ^/       \/ \
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-l`, 100 bytes

```
Y#aZGMXaFi,#aIh:+a@i{(yi--h):4j:0Wh-j&++(yi-++jh-j)(yi+jh-j):2}RV Z(J*y)R`.(?=.*[^0])`0R,6;^" /\v^^"
```

*(The language is newer than the question, but probably isn't going to beat the APL submission anyway. Although I hope it will get much shorter.)*

Takes input via command-line argument. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/Ujkxyt03ItEtU0c50TPDSjvRIbNaozJTVzdD08oky8ogPEM3S01bGySkrZ0F5GgCmRCGlVFtUJhClIaXVqVmUIKehr2tnlZ0nEGsZoJBkI6ZdZySgn5MWVyc0v///3Vz/hvq6emZALExCBuD2SCunhFQxMgIJGSqB2KAZEEiIHE9QwA)