# Quoting Big Brother

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, restricted-source, random

Task: Have your program randomly choose one of the following two quotes at runtime and print that one quote, exactly as shown.

1:

```
Under the spreading chestnut tree
I sold you and you sold me.
There lie they, and here lie we
Under the spreading chestnut tree.
```

2:

```
WAR IS PEACE.
FREEDOM IS SLAVERY.
IGNORANCE IS STRENGTH.
```

Restrictions: The words `spreading`, `chestnut`, `PEACE`, `FREEDOM`, and `STRENGTH` **must** appear in your code. No word from the above two quotes may appear in your code **more than once**.

Shortest solution wins.

Comment: Ok I choosed the first. Honest! http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: @edc65 That's [no longer funny](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1739/8478).

Comment: @MartinBüttner not to be funny, but to suggest a more explicit rule. Reading first time I really tought I could choose a random one and then start to work.

Comment: @edc65 Ah I see, the wording used to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PHP 179

Inspired by [es1024's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35591/21202) answer.

```php
<?=strtr(rand()%2?"0
I 1 232 1 me.
T5 they,35 we
0.
":"WAR4PEACE.
FREEDOM4SLAVERY.
IGNORANCE4STRENGTH.
",["Under the spreading chestnut tree",sold,you," and "," IS ","here lie"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl (<s>191</s> 184 characters)

```perl
$_=$$&1?"0
I12321me6T4they,34we
06":"WAR5PEACE6FREEDOM5SLAVERY6IGNORANCE5STRENGTH6";s/\d/("Under the spreading chestnut tree"," sold ",you," and ","here lie "," IS ",".
")[$&]/ge;print
```

Thanks @core1024 for tips on golfing this.

Comment: You can replace 6 with actual new lines, drop the quotes around `"you"` and use `$$&1` as a random generator :)

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 338

I can't get it below 338...

```
class B{public static void main(String[]a){String b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=".\n",i=" IS ";if(Math.random()>.5)System.out.print(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+h);else System.out.print("WAR"+i+"PEACE"+h+"FREEDOM"+i+"SLAVERY"+h+"IGNORANCE"+i+"STRENGTH"+h);}}
```

Bit ungolfed:

```
class B{public static void main(String[]a){String b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=".\n",i=" IS ";
if(Math.random()>.5)System.out.print(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+h);
else System.out.print("WAR"+i+"PEACE"+h+"FREEDOM"+i+"SLAVERY"+h+"IGNORANCE"+i+"STRENGTH"+h);}}
```

Comment: Yes you can http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Gonna search for something useful tomorrow.

Comment: @Fabinout I've tried a few tricks, but they didn't help. (`java.io.PrintStream p=System.out`, added 15 bytes to total, `static<T>void p(T o){System.out.print(o);}`, added 12). Any other suggestions?

Comment: use static block instead of a main declaration

Comment: Static block *310 CHAR *: class B{static{String b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=".\n",i=" IS ";if(Math.random()>.5)System.out.print(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+h);else System.out.print("WAR"+i+"PEACE"+h+"FREEDOM"+i+"SLAVERY"+h+"IGNORANCE"+i+"STRENGTH"+h);}}

Comment: Unfortunately, that trick doesn't work in Java 8. Guess I should have specified that :)

Comment: Java 6 is the price to pay for golfing in Java 8)

Comment: I know it's been more than 2 years, but you can golf it by printing just once with a ternary if and since you talked about Java 8 in the comment above, you can also replace `class` with `interface` and remove the `public ` before the main-method: `interface B{static void main(String[]a){String b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=".\n",i=" IS ";System.out.print(Math.random()>.5?b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+h:"WAR"+i+"PEACE"+h+"FREEDOM"+i+"SLAVERY"+h+"IGNORANCE"+i+"STRENGTH"+h);}}` (**308 bytes**)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 229 <s>254 256</s>

**Edit 1** using `new Date` as suggested by @Doorknob - still unclear to me how javascript Dates morph to strings or integers or whatever

**Edit 2** simplified. A lot.

```
t=(new Date&1
   ?'0WAR0 IS 0PEACE0.\n0FREEDOM020SLAVERY040IGNORANCE020STRENGTH.'
   :'0Under the spreading chestnut tree0\nI 0sold 0you 0and 04030me.\nT0here lie 0they, 05090we\n010.'
  ).split(0);
for(i=o='';j=t[++i];)o+=t[j|0||i];alert(o)
```

Comment: `new Date` is shorter than `Date.now()`

Comment: To explain the `Date` conversion: *> [The JavaScript date is  based on a time value that is milliseconds since midnight 01 January, 1970 UTC. A day holds 86,400,000 milliseconds. The JavaScript Date object range is -100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days relative to 01 January, 1970 UTC.*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), when you `&` it it's automatically cast to a `Number`. So you're basically making the random choice based on whether it's an even or odd millisecond since the `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` epoch.

Comment: @Doorknob could you write a short article for that shorter random number generator in https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript Haven't seen it there yet and I think it could be quite useful.

Comment: @flawr [Done](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/35648/3808)

Answer (score 2):

## C# <strike>(268)(260)</strike> (256)

This is executable in LINQPad, using the `Dump()` method:

```
string b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";if(new Random().Next(9)>4)(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+".").Dump();else("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.").Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
string b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";

if(new Random().Next(9)>4)
    (b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+".").Dump();
else
    ("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.").Dump();
```

**Update:**

Using the ternary operator and 1 extra variable, I was able to cut another 6 characters:

```
string a,b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";a=new Random().Next(9)>4?(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+"."):("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.");a.Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
string a,b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";

a=new Random().Next(9)>4 ?
    (b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+".") :
    ("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.");

a.Dump();
```

**Update2:**

Thanks to the ingenious suggestion of `tsavinho` I was able to save 4 more chars by placing braces around the ternary operation:

```
string b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";(new Random().Next(9)>4?(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+"."):("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.")).Dump();
```

Ungolfed:

```
string b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";
(new Random().Next(9)>4?
    (b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+"."):
    ("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.")
).Dump();
```

Comment: You could save 4 more characters by removing a and replacing it with brackets like this:
string b="Under the spreading chestnut tree",c="sold ",d="you ",e="and ",f="me.\nT",g="here lie ",h=" IS ";(new Random().Next(9)>4?(b+"\nI "+c+d+e+d+c+f+g+"they, "+e+g+"we\n"+b+"."):("WAR"+h+"PEACE.\nFREEDOM"+h+"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE"+h+"STRENGTH.")).Dump();

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3 - 228

```python
for x in[b"AB:87078@624>049BA6",b"?;<61;=63;56"][id(id)%3-1]:print("and |FREEDOM|T|IGNORANCE|here lie |STRENGTH|.\n|you |sold |we|I | IS |PEACE|SLAVERY|they, |WAR|me|Under the spreading chestnut tree|\n".split("|")[x-48],end="")
```

Slightly ungolfed:

```python
# id(id) returns an even number based on memory address of id
# id(id)%3-1 gives -1, 0 or 1
randomNumber = id(id)%3-1

# Word list
words = "and |FREEDOM|T|IGNORANCE|here lie |STRENGTH|.\n|you |sold |we|I | IS |PEACE|SLAVERY|they, |WAR|me|Under the spreading chestnut tree|\n".split("|")

# Byte Literals for Under the chestnut and WAR IS PEACE
# each byte correspond to the word's index in the word list
byteLiterals = [b"AB:87078@624>049BA6", b"?;<61;=63;56"]
choice = byteLiterals[randomNumber]

for x in choice: 
    print(words[x-48], end="") # Print each word out
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell 205

```
("{0}.`nI{1}{2}{3}{2}{1} me.`nT{4}they,{3} {4}we`n{0}."-f"Under the spreading chestnut tree"," sold"," you"," and","here lie "),("WAR","PEACE.`nFREEDOM","SLAVERY.`nIGNORANCE","STRENGTH."-join" IS ")|Random
```

Uses the `-f` operator to put strings on the first quote, and the second one is joined by `IS`, after that it selects a random element of those 2 quotes and prints it...

Comment: [Easy 5 bytes by swapping out the `ns](https://tio.run/##HY7BDoIwEETvfMWmJ02QiPoDRCuSKJqCGo9GVsFAawrGkNpvx62XnZ23m8m81Ad1W2JdD8OImakNvMSE1sysmf9naKHBwMvNwnYl9j5hoP2Dnntmkzs7ygI10BHal8ZrUckH3EpsO/nuoNOIzGfQqrpw2qu3k6t0rkSNUFcIbOyP2DkSxA48WvLAWwvOV/sdgWwbnbi4UK843YsoXXIHc8HTON9QgaeqJIMko5CvoFzVDMMP "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript / jQuery 396

```
var B={
U:"Under the spreading chestnut tree",
s:"sold ",
y:"you ",
l:"lie ",
a:"and ",
i:"IS ",
b:"</br>"
};
var A={
P:B.U+B.b+"I "+B.s+B.y+B.a+B.y+B.s+"me."+B.b
+"There "+B.l+"they, "+B.a+"here "+B.l+"we."+B.b+B.U,
Q:"WAR "+B.i+"PEACE."+B.b+"FREEDOM "+B.i+"SLAVERY."+B.b
+"IGNORANCE "+B.i+"STRENGTH."
};
$(function(){
var z=(Math.random()<0.5)?A.P:A.Q; 
$('#d').append(z);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, <del>337</del> 327

Just for fun, I've made another solution in T-SQL, which is one byte shorter than my Java 8 solution:

```
DECLARE @b char(33)='Under the spreading chestnut tree',@c char(5)='sold',@d char(4)='you',@e char(4)='and',@f char(9)='here lie',@ char='
',@h char(4)=' IS'IF rand()>.5PRINT @b+@+'I '+@c+@d+@e+@d+@c+'me.'+@+'T'+@f+'they, '+@e+@f+'we'+@+@b+'.'ELSE PRINT'WAR'+@h+'PEACE.'+@+'FREEDOM'+@h+'SLAVERY.'+@+'IGNORANCE'+@h+'STRENGTH.'
```

By declaring the `char`s one too long, you can add an 'automatic' space, saving up a few bytes.

Using the code in the proposed edit by user PenutReaper, you can indeed shave off 10 bytes.

Comment: Using a variable for carriage returns isn't worth it.  Just use literal ones.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 233 bytes

```
Math.random()>0.5?(a="Under the spreading chestnut tree")+"\nI "+(s="sold")+(y=" you ")+(n="and")+y+s+" me.\nT"+(h="here ")+(l="lie ")+"they "+n+" "+h+l+"we\n"+a+".":["WAR","PEACE.\nFREEDOM","SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE","STRENGTH."].join(" IS ")
```

Wrote this without looking at other answers. Makes good use of assignments as expressions.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>307</s> <s>289</s> <s>271</s> 270 bytes

-37 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```c
*y=" IS ";main(){int*r[]={"WAR",y,"PEACE.\nFREEDOM",y,"SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE",y,"STRENGTH.",0,"Under the spreading chestnut tree","\nI"," sold ","you"," and ",r[11],r[10],"me.\n","T","here lie ","they,",r[12],r[17],"we\n",r[8],".",0},z=r;for(z=z/2&8;r[z];)printf(r[z++]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU/BbsIwDP2VKIephYwBlyFFPVQsY0hbmUK3aepyqFpDK0GK3KCpRXx757CDLb/n52e7uN8XxTCMuoiz9ZZxecxrG4SX2roRZia68K9Yc9EJ/q7ipZr82Get1NPm7cZtX@NPpb@JXa@SjY6TpfrnU62SVfoy4WIq@IctAZmrgLUnhLys7Z4VFbTOnh1zCMAFJwfKrG0OJaOia84e5tYjzGYz4/PUCH4E2ka9lKICBHaowU@QPS32qvlN@0jaX/BSzBZU@1Ouoo9Q7hoM@qh/mN8tJGa9keEJ6d1dQGA8NqG8DsMf)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 119 bytes

```
“‚â€€ spreading chestnutíÍ““Iïê€î€ƒ€îïê€á.““€Çº¤€»,€ƒ€Îº¤€¦“).ªĆ»‘‡î€ˆ PEACE.
FREEDOM€ˆÃÒRY.
IGNORANCE€ˆ STRENGTH‘)'.«Ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcRw2zDi961LQGiBSKC4pSE1My89IVkjNSi0vySksOrz3cC1Y0x/Pw@sOrgIoOrwMSxyaBWTChhXoQNSB2@6Fdh5YAGYd268AV9sHElgEVaeodWnWk7dDuRw0zHjUsBBt3uk0hwNXR2VWPyy3I1dXF3xcsdrj58KSgSD0uT3c//yBHP2dXiMrgkCBXP/cQD6B@TXW9Q6vPrfz/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 222 bytes

```python
a,b,c,d,e,f='Under the spreading chestnut tree',' you ',' lie ','and','sold',' IS '
print({f'{a}\nI {e}{b}{d}{b}{e} me.\nThere{c}they, {d} here{c}we\n{a}.',f'WAR{f}PEACE.\nFREEDOM{f}SLAVERY.\nIGNORANCE{f}STRENGTH.'}.pop())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3BCsIwEETvfsXeohB68eyhaNSCVolVEXqpzdYWdBvSiJSQb6@peJkHbxhG97ZuaT4MBb/zkiuOvFqwMyk0YGuEThssVEMPKGvsLL0tWIPIOIO@fcPIZ4MjC1Ihu/Y5ApITsIk2Ddmpq5grfE4JOPTu7p36JXp4YZRTVqNBV/rw1nMIJfzFB3MKw4jxil1j6Sp/FPFShMlaCrE67IM57eKLkLfgkk16kHG6FKPNpEg32TZiPtKtns5mw/AF)