# Print all odd numbers from 0 to 100000

Tags: code-golf, number, tips, javascript

My teacher gave me a simple problem which I should solve with a code tiny as possible. I should print all odd numbers from 0 to 100000 into a HTML document using javascript.

```
for(var y = 0; y < 100000; y++){
if(!(y % 2 == 0)){
document.write(y + " ");
}
};
```

Is it possible to do that shorter?

Comment: By shorter do you mean Javascript only or any language?

Comment: The problem should be solved in JS only.

Comment: -1 for needlessly restriction on the language

Comment: @JohannesKuhn [language-specific questions asking for golfing advice are perfectly on-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1724/8478)

Comment: -1 for asking us to do your homework better.

Comment: The non-golfed Perl6 answer would be: `say "{ 1, 3, 5, 7 ...^ *>100000 }"` The golfed version would be: `say "{1,3...9 x 5}"` or `say "{1,3...99999}"`

Comment: Read this: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript

Comment: Did you teacher specify that _only_ the odd numbers were to be printed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## JavaScript, 38 bytes

Yet another way to do this, shortest of all.

This supposedly prints each number on a new line using `\n`. Now as the data is being written to an HTML document, `\n` is not of any use and the numbers appear to be separated by space only.

```js
for(i=1;i<1e5;i+=2)document.writeln(i)
```

Comment: Just edit your existing answer(s)

Comment: @proudhaskeller more rep this way ;)

Comment: Or the alternative `for(i=0;++i<1e5;)document.writeln(i++)`. I've found plenty, but none beats 38. Good job.

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript, 36 bytes

If order doesn't matter:

```js
for(i=1e5;i--;)document.writeln(i--)
```

Writes the numbers in reverse order.

Answer (score 6):

another way to do it in 38 bytes:

```
for(i=0;i<5e4;)document.writeln(i+++i)
```

explanation:`i+++i` means the same as `(i++)+i`, with the second `i` resolving to its new value (as effected by the ++) so it goes like this for the results:

- 0+1=`1`
- 1+2=`3`
- 2+3=`5`

etc...

Comment: Can you explain the `i+++i` condition? Thanks

Comment: @NiCkNewman  see edit.

Comment: Learn something new everyday, thanks Jasen.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 40 bytes

```js
for(i=1;i<1e5;i+=2)document.write(i+" ")
```

The code is fairly straight forward.

- I iterate from `i=1` to `i=1e5`. `1e5` is nothing but `1` followed by 5 `0`, so `100000`.
- In each iteration step, I print the value of `i` and increment `i` by `2`. Thus printing only every other number starting from `1` and till `100000`.

This prints all the odd numbers from `1` to `100000`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 40 bytes

Another way to do it!

```js
for(i=0;i<5e4;)document.writeln(2*++i-1)
```

The code is fairly straight forward.

- Iterate from `i = 0` to `i = 5e4`. `5e4` is nothing but `5` followed by 4 `0`, so `50000`.
- In each iteration step, print the value of `2*i - 1` after incrementing `i` by `1`. Thus printing only odd numbers from `1` to `99999`.

Answer (score 0):

**Using while** 42

```
i=-1;while((i+=2)<10e5)document.writeln(i)
```