# Golf a Compute interpreter

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

## Introduction

Compute is a <s>esoteric</s> joke language.

From the [esolangs entry:](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Compute)

> Compute has no required syntax and has the power to solve any and all
> problems. It is smart enough to interpret any human language (English,
> Spanish, Latin, etc), any programming language (C++, Java, brainfuck,
> etc), or any kind of data you can think of. **The only downfall is that
> there is absolutely no I/O.**

#### Some example programs

```
Hello World
```

A basic Hello World program

```
What is love?
```

Determines was love is (baby don't hurt me).

```
When will we ever graduate?
```

Determines the exact date of this site to get out of beta.

## The Challenge

Your task is to write a full Compute interpreter. This sounds pretty hard, but keep in mind that Compute has absolutly no I/O. So your interpreter will just sleep one second for every **line** in the input program and output `\n\nDone.` after this (this is the only exception to the no I/O thing).

You can find the official interpreter at the bottom of [this site](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Compute).
*Note that the official interpreter pauses one second for every character in the given source code. To avoid long waiting times while testing your interpreter with meaningful questions **we stay with lines** in this challenge.*

## Rules

- The input might contain multiple lines seperated by a `\n`. There will always be at least one line.
- Unlike the official implementation you don't have to take a file as input. You can take the Compute program in any form of input you want.
- The only output allowed is `\n\nDone.`. A trailing newline is allowed.
- Function or full program allowed.
- [Default rules](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) for input/output.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so lowest byte-count wins. Tiebreaker is earlier submission.

Comment: Inevitably reminded me of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IY2j_GPIqRA)

Comment: @LuisMendo This is glorious! I almost lost it.

Comment: Well, we don't need a program to tell us when we're going to graduate. We already know that it's the 26th.

Comment: I think the interpreter sleeps a second for each _character_ in source code.

Comment: @Doorknob, of what century?

Comment: @DenkerAffe I think you should make it clear that the challenge does not exactly match the language.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Pietu1998 means the chars/lines thing.

Comment: @msh210, no, that is the century.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Code:

```
[Ig>#w’

D€µ.
```

Explanation:

```
[        # Starts an infinite loop
 I       # Input string
  g>     # Length + 1
    #    # If equal to 1, break out of the loop
     w   # Wait 1 second
```

This part is equivalent to `"\n\nDone."`:

```
      ’  # Push "\n\nDone." on top of the stack

D€µ.     # The compressed string is ended implicitly
         # Implicit, print top of the stack
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W0lnPiN34oCZCgpE4oKswrUu&input=SGVsbG8KV29ybGQKCg)

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript Shell REPL, 38 bytes

As a function that accepts the program as a string argument and returns the result:

```
s=>sleep(s.split`
`.length)||`

Done.`
```

29 bytes if the function can accept its input in the form of an array of lines, or if it should sleep 1 second per character:

```
s=>sleep(s.length)||`

Done.`
```

34 bytes if it should also be more like a program and explicitly print Done:

```
s=>sleep(s.length)||print`

Done.`
```

This works for me in the standalone Spidermonkey interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript ES6, <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
a=>setTimeout(x=>alert`

Done.`,a.length*1e3)
```

Thanks to [ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41247/%D3%8D%D1%B2%EA%9D%86%CE%9B%D2%90%D3%8D%CE%9B%D0%9F%D2%92%D0%A6%EA%9D%86) for saving one byte

Assumes an array as input.

As both [ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41247/%D3%8D%D1%B2%EA%9D%86%CE%9B%D2%90%D3%8D%CE%9B%D0%9F%D2%92%D0%A6%EA%9D%86) and [edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65) have pointed out you can write the following, but it won't save any bytes:

```
a=>setTimeout("alert`\n\nDone`",a.length*1e3)
```

Comment: `1e3` is better than `10e2`.

Comment: Also, convert the arrow function to a string. See http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60960/41247

Comment: @ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ  I'm not sure that would work. Since he already has a template string, you would need to escape it

Comment: @ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ `1e3 is better than 10e2` can't believe i missed that .

Comment: @edc65 You are not the first to talk about it, ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ also mentioned it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 28

```
sleep `wc -l`
echo "

Done."
```

Sleeps 1 second for every line.  Use `wc -c` instead for every byte, or `wc -m` instead for every character.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an extra newline?

Comment: @immibis Yes - you're right - fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Oration](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Assorted-Programming-Languages/tree/master/oration), 117 bytes

```
I need time!
To iterate, input().
Inhale.
Now sleep(1).
Backtracking.
Boring,
boring.
Listen!
Capture Done.
Carry on!
```

Let's explain this. First, this transpiles to:

```
import time
while input():
    time.sleep(1)
print("\n")
print("\n")
print("Done")
```

Still confused? Let's put it like this:

```
I need time!
```

Imports the module `time`.

```
To iterate, input().
```

This is a while loop whose condition is `input()`.

```
Inhale.
```

Our program needs to breathe now, and `inhale`, whilst less healthy, is golfier.

```
Now sleep(1).
```

`Now` take the most recent module imported and appends `.sleep(1)` to it.

```
Backtracking.
```

Let's exit the while loop.

```
Boring,
boring.
```

Prints two newlines.

```
Listen!
```

Begins capturing a string.

```
Capture Done.
```

Adds `Done.` to the captured string.

```
Carry on!
```

Finishes capturing string.

Comment: Looks like a fun language. Would you add a link to an interpreter + docs?

Comment: @DenkerAffe The docs and interpreter can both be found in the heading I just edited in.

Comment: @Conor Thanks, gonna have a look at it. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
.dcl.z1b"Done.
```

<sup><sup>(You can [try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.dcl.z1b%22Done.&debug=0), but there's really no point in doing so.)</sup></sup>

Comment: You are missing the period after `Done` (which is pretty funny since you told someone the same on another answer) :P

Comment: @DenkerAffe Thanks. (Byte count was correct, though.)

Comment: @muddyfish Thats what the challenge says. The official interpreter goes char-wise, but I changed it to lines to avoid waiting times.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Ok now our entries our exactly the same. Whos to keep? I'm going to assume Pietu1998 because they were correct first

Comment: Is b necessary?

Comment: @busukxuan Yes, to print the newlines.

Comment: I think everyone hates Pyth by now....

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 17 bytes

```
10c'Done.'`jt?1Y.
```

A trailing empty line (followed by newline) is used to mark end of input. This is needed in MATL because input is interactive and each input ends with a newline.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MTBjJ0RvbmUuJ2BqdD8xWS4&input=RmluZCB0aGUgVWx0aW1hdGUgUXVlc3Rpb24gb2YgTGlmZSwgdGhlIFVuaXZlcnNlLCBhbmQgRXZlcnl0aGluZwpPbiBzZWNvbmQgdGhvdWdodCwgZG9uJ3QKCgo)

```
10c           % push newline character
'Done.'       % push string
`             % do...while
  j           % input string
  t           % duplicate
  ?           % if non-empty
    1Y.       % pause for 1 second
              % loop condition is the current string. If non-empty: next iteration
              % If empty: exit loop and print stack contents. There are two strings
              % and a newline is printed after each, so the desired output is obtained
```

Comment: Are you missing the period after `Done`?

Comment: @Pietu1998 Whoops. Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 21 + 1 = 22 bytes

```
sleep 1}{$_="\n\nDone."
```

Requires the `-p` flag:

```
$ perl -pe'sleep 1}{$_="\n\nDone."' <<< $'a\nb\nc'


Done.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 58 bytes

```
import time
while input():time.sleep(1)
print("\n\nDone.")
```

Comment: Just wanna point this out, it would be 2 Bytes shorter in python 2, print"\n\nDone"

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot... Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

## QBasic, 54 bytes

```
LINE INPUT x$
IF x$=""GOTO 1
SLEEP 1
RUN
1?
?
?"Done."
```

Takes the program line by line from user input, terminated by a blank line. Abides by the letter of the law, though possibly not the spirit, by pausing 1 second after reading each line. (The specification doesn't technically say that the pauses all have to come after the input is completed.) If this is considered too shady, here's a 64-byte version that pauses after the whole program has been input:

```
DO
LINE INPUT x$
IF x$=""GOTO 1
t=t+1
LOOP
1SLEEP t
?
?
?"Done."
```

---

Bonus version with file I/O (87 bytes):

```
INPUT f$
OPEN f$FOR INPUT AS 1
1LINE INPUT #1,x$
SLEEP 1
IF 0=EOF(1)GOTO 1
?
?
?"Done."
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 32 bytes

```
$<.map{sleep 1}
puts"\n\nDone."
```

Reads from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

## OCaml, 61 bytes

```
fun a->List.iter(fun _->Unix.sleep 1)a;print_string"\n\nDone"
```

Assumes the input is a list.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ỴLœS@⁷⁷“ẋḲp»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w9xafo5ODHR41bgehhjkPd3U/3LGp4NDu////e6Tm5OQrhOcX5aRwhWcklihkFivk5Jel2gN5qXkK5Zk5OQrlqQqpZalFCulFiSmliSWp9gA)

Note: Please **do not** suggest putting the `⁷⁷` in the compressed string, it will make it longer (`“¡OÑL[Ṁ»`).

Explanation:

```
ỴLœS@⁷⁷“ẋḲp» Main link. Arguments: z.
ỴL           The number of lines in z. (x)
     ⁷       Newline ("\n") (y)
  œS@        After sleeping for x seconds, return y.
      ⁷      Newline ("\n")
       “ẋḲp» Compressed string ("Done.")
```

Answer (score 0):

### awk, 34 bytes

```
END{print"\nDone."|"cat;sleep "NR}
```

As there is no I/O and the final outcome is inevitable,  the `Done.` part is outputed right in the beginning.

```
$ awk 'END{print"\nDone."|"cat;sleep "NR}' file
```

Only way to sleep in awk is to use system `sleep`. Shortest way to invocate it is to `print|"sleep "NR` and we might as well abuse that useless `print`.