# Permutation? Permutatino!

Tags: code-challenge, permutations

### Specifications

Your program <strike>must</strike> can take in an integer `n`, then take in `n` more strings (containing only alphanumeric characters) in your preferred method (separated by whitespace, file input, hash table etc.). You must then find the permutation before the inputted strings when sorted in lexicographical order, and output that in your preferred method.

If it is already sorted in lexicographical order, output the permutation in <strike>reverse</strike> regular lexicographical order.

#### Rules

1. Code can be just a function
2. If you pipe in from a file, you can to exclude the file name's length from your program (just the filename, not full path)
3. If there are repeated characters, take the permutation before the first occurrence of the repeats

#### Test cases

```
3 abc hi def
```

The possible permutations of this (in lexicographical order) are:

```
abc def hi
abc hi def
def abc hi
def hi abc
hi abc def
hi def abc
```

Now see that `abc hi def` is the 2nd permutation, so we output `abc def hi`.

If instead we pick `abc def hi`(the first permutation), then output `abc def hi`.

Another test case is in the title: your function should map `Permutation` to `Permutatino`

#### Scoring:

The winner is the code with the smallest score, which is the length of the code multiplied by the bonus.

#### Bonus:

<strike>20%</strike> -90% (to keep non-esolangs in the fight) of your byte count if you can do this in O(N) time.

-50% (stacks with the above -90% to give a total of -95%) if your solution isn't O(N!) which is listing out permutations, finding the element and getting the index, subtracting 1 from the index (keep it the same if the index is 0) and outputting the element with the subtracted index

With the above 2 bonuses, I won't be surprised if there's a 2 byte answer.

Hint: there is definitely a faster way to do this apart from listing all the permutations and finding the supposed element in the general case

Congrats to @Forty3 for being the first person to get the O(N) solution!

Here's some (C based) pseudocode:

```
F(A) { // A[0..n-1] stores a permutation of {1, 2, .., n}
  int i, j;
  for (i = n - 1; i > 0 && (A[i-1] < A[i]); i--)
    ; // empty statement
  if (i = 0)
    return 0;
  for (j = i + 1; j < n && (A[i-1] > A[j]); j++)
    ; // empty statement
  swap(A[i-1], A[j-1]); // swap values in the two entries
  reverse(A[i..n-1]); // reverse entries in the subarray
  return 1;
}
```

If you want to test if your program is O(N), try with `n=11` and the strings being the individual letters of `Permutation`. If it takes longer than a second, it's most definitely not O(N).

Comment: Can we get more test cases?

Comment: @Okx If you test with the individual characters of the word "Permutation" and you get "Permutatino", then it's good. Of course, you have to wait about 5 hours if your solution isn't O(N). Other than that I'm a bit too lazy to add more test cases.

Comment: C++ has a linear time builtin for that but sadly even using that won't come close to a golfing language. Moreover: do you consider string compares to be a single step ?

Comment: Can we choose to only support char arrays as input, not string arrays?

Comment: @Okx My interpretation of that comment is that you want to only support chars instead of strings. In that case, no. If you can then extend that to support char array arrays, then yes.

Comment: @Christoph String compares are O(N), sum of O(N) and O(1) functions is still O(N). It really doesn't matter.

Comment: Where is the wrap around gone?

Comment: @GB It has disappeared into the garbage void. You don't have to handle wrap around anymore, now you have to handle special case when it's the first element

Comment: @Thunda My solution implements wrap-around since I wrote it before the spec change. Can i keep that behaviour?

Comment: @math_junkie yes, but it would be nice if you could add another solution :)

Comment: [Things to avoid when writing challenges: Bonuses in code-golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8106/34718)

Comment: @mbomb007 I'll keep that in mind before making about 20 edits to my question next time.

Comment: In meta there is a "sandbox" where you can post an idea for a challenge and get feedback.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>118</s> 96 - 50% = 48 bytes

Takes input in the form `['abc','def','ghi']`. Note that this solution returns the list reversed if the input is sorted, as per a previous spec.

```py
def f(n):m=n[1:];S=sorted;a=S(n);return[a.pop(a.index(n[0])-1)]+a[::-1]if m==S(m)else[n[0]]+f(m)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Lc1BCsQgDAXQq3RnpdMybhVP0WXIQjCCMEaxFub2NgOzeHyS8MmMlJa0srbFMxiL7vRX7YOiC/6Uves07s4QjlbbGo7Mkb4rwxv1bjRuAazdDea0FC@FoulzEfzuuCUZZ@uZh7wA1dRLkeiiiFsMEf6ZRRWsUM8H)

Seems to be <s>the O(n) solution</s> more efficient than computing all permutations.

**Explanation:** Recursively checks if everything after the current element is in `sorted` order. If so, returns the string immediately lexicographically before (`a.index(n[0])-1)`) the first element `+` the rest of the list reversed (`a[::-1]`).

**Runtime: O(n^2 logn)** In the worst case (list is reversed), the function will call `sorted`, which has a runtime of **nlogn**, for each element in the list (`n` times).

Comment: I didn't count this specifically but I believe you can save 2 bytes by extracting `sorted` to a variable. You can also remove the unnecessary space between `return [b]`. Otherwise, nice solution!

Comment: What do you take as input?

Comment: Surely, `sorted` can't have a worst-case performance better than O(*n* log *n*) for large enough problem sizes.

Comment: Using `sorted()` definitely makes this non O(n)

Comment: If you can prove that this isn't O(N!) then you can have a -50% byte reduction.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <strike>460</strike> <strike>399</strike> <strike>369</strike> 332 - 95% = 16.6 bytes

### Unformatted

```
function f(n,v){var i=n-1,c=v[i],z="concat",y="slice",x="indexOf",w="reverse";for(;i>=0&&v[i]<=c;i--){c=v[i];}if(i==-1)return v;if(i==0){let s=v[z]().sort(),t=s[x](v[i])-1;return [s[t]][z]((s[y](0,t)[z](s[y](t+1)))[w]());}let p=v[y](0,i),r=v[y](i)[z]().sort()[w](),t=r[x](v[i])+1,m=r[t];r.splice(t-1,2,v[i]);return p[z]([m])[z](r);}
```

I am not convinced it is the O(n) solution but would appreciate if someone could take a quick glance and let me know. Also, I suspect there is some serious golfing which can be accomplished.. just haven't taken the time (yet).

### Formatted

```
function f2(n, v) {
  var i = n-1,c = v[i],z="concat",y="slice",x="indexOf",w="reverse";
  for ( ; i >= 0 && v[i] <= c; i--) {
    c = v[i];
  }
  if (i == -1) return v;
  if (i == 0) {
    let s = v[z]().sort(), t = s[x](v[i]) - 1;
    return [s[t]][z]((s[y](0, t)[z](s[y](t + 1)))[w]());
  }

  let p = v[y](0,i),
  r = v[y](i)[z]().sort()[w](),
  t = r[x](v[i])+1,
  m = r[t];
  r.splice(t-1,2,v[i]);
  return p[z]([m])[z](r);

}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2Lmswxf/8/

Edit 1 - whitespace and function name per @Emigna's suggestions.

Edit 2 - using some pointers from the link @Emigna suggested. If I *ever* found this code in a system I had to maintain, I would hunt the developer down and flog him.

Edit 3 - @Thunda - I hope it wasn't presumptuous to recalc the savings based on my latest golfing.

Edit 4 - Removed a sort and simplified the final reassembly logic.

Comment: Just removing the unnecessary whitespace and renaming the function to `r` saves 61 bytes. There are probably some [tips from here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2682/47066) that could help you save even more.

Comment: I just tried with 26 characters (the alphabet, obviously) and it's wayyyyyyyy faster than all the other answers. Great, it's O(N), it's pretty much the algorithm that I used.

Comment: Can you provide complexity of sort, used here? I might guess, that it is bigger, that O(N). @Thunda, you should not judge complexity by speed of evaluation. There is a definition for O-notation.

Comment: @DeadPossum It's definitely O(N) (as far as I can tell). It's a bunch of O(N) loops (and splice) with a couple O(1) functions sprinkled about. Could definitely do with an explanation though. If you go into the fiddle provided and copy paste a (ridiculous amount) of strings, then it would definitely be faster than the current best O(N^2 log n) solution.

Comment: @Thunda Same question again - name complexity of `sort` function

Comment: @DeadPossum The sort function isn't relevant here, as the N is about the number of elements, not the length of the strings in question (unless my big O is rusty). Sort will have O(n log n) where n is the length of the string.

Comment: @Thunda Sort used here three times in different context. I believe, that it might be used not only for strings but for lists too. Detailed explanation of code is needed first to decide anything.

Comment: @DeadPossum - I added some comments to Fiddle v5 (https://jsfiddle.net/n2Lmswxf/5/) in hopes of clearing things up. There are, as best as I can tell, a maximum of two sorts. But they could be expensive in and of themselves. I might be able to reduce one of them at the cost of code length.

Comment: Thank you. At least your 2nd special case won't work at O(n) as it sorts array of values just one shorter than input. And so the whole answer can't be treated as O(n)

Comment: @DeadPossum - So, O(n log n), then?

Comment: @Forty3 Yes, that would be right estimate

Comment: Based on the explanation on Fiddle, this algorithm looks to be the same efficiency as [mine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114127/65425)

Comment: Then back to -50%? God I really shouldn't have put these bonuses in

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> 8 bytes

```
œ{ûD¹k<è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@390cvXh3S6HdmbbHF7x/3@0emJSsrqOgnpGJohMSU1TjwUA)

**Explanation**

```
œ{           # get a list of sorted permutations of the input
  û          # append a reversed copy excepting the last element of the original
   D         # duplicate
    ¹k       # push the first index of the input in the list
      <      # decrement
       è     # index into the list with this
```

Comment: With esolang answers this short, I think I need to up the bonus for an O(n) solution. This is ridiculously slow.

Comment: @Thunda: Yeah. As it calculates all permutations, the computation time increases drastically the more strings there are in the input :P

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 83 bytes

-18 bytes, thanks to @Emigna

Takes strings without number as input. As rules were clarified, this is the solution.
[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RczBCsIwDMbx@54i4KGtU8Gr4mGXvcTYYdoMC7YpSQTfvrYy8BI@fn9IWZkiBEVWopdAiJlY953HFUY7uIvcpAJ6m5HjWxcNlKQG10/DfM0ckoJMcgrJ46f68TyX0Vqz3B/mAOYZ2q3fjHNd8zar/PPmG2z55wCwI/bI6MsX)

```
from itertools import*
def F(A):s=sorted(permutations(A))+[A];print s[s.index(A)-1]
```

Comment: To clarify, if the input string is ordered, it should output the input string

Comment: You could save 18 bytes [like this](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RczBCsIwDMbx@54i4KGtU8Gr4mGXvcTYYdoMC7YpSQTfvrYy8BI@fn9IWZkiBEVWopdAiJlY953HFUY7uIvcpAJ6m5HjWxcNlKQG10/DfM0ckoJMcgrJ46f68TyX0Vqz3B/mAOYZ2q3fjHNd8zar/PPmG2z55wCwI/bI6MsX)

Comment: @Emigna Thank you, this is neat

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 - 50% = 4 bytes

```
Œ¿’»1œ?Ṣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3900qH9jxpmHtpteHSy/cOdi/7//x@tVKCko5QKxEVAnAvEpUBcAsSJUDoTiPOBOE8pFgA)

Runs in O(*n* log *n*) time. (This typically takes just over a second, due mostly to Jelly's startup time – the time of just over a second is true for both very short and fairly long inputs. There's some variation in how long it takes in TIO; the fastest I've observed is 0.914 real, 0.772 user, 0.121 system.)

### Explanation

Jelly actually has builtins for most of the challenge, but the way they're defined requires a sort. As far as I know, Jelly uses a comparison sort to sort lists of strings, which is what leads to the O(*n* log *n*) performance.

```
Œ¿’»1œ?Ṣ
Œ¿         Find index of {the input} in a sorted list of its permutations
  ’        Decrement it
   »1      saturating from below at 1
     œ?    Find the nth permutation of
       Ṣ   the sorted input
```

`Œ¿` is a builtin with an optimized implementation (i.e. not slower than O(*n* log *n*)); it doesn't do brute-forcing.

### Variations

If wrap-around is allowed (it was under an earlier version of the spec), you can remove the `»1` for a 6-byte solution and a score of 3. (Most of Jelly's builtins, including the relevant ones here, will naturally wrap around in the absence of other hints about what to do with an out-of-range value.)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 170 - 95% = 8.5 bytes

```js
f=n=>a=>{while(--n&&a[n]>=a[n-1]);if(!n)return a;s=a.slice(--n);for(k=s.length;s[--k]>=a[n];);t=a[n];s[0]=s[k];s[k]=t;return a.slice(0,n).concat(s[0],s.slice(1).reverse())}

function Permutatino() {
  input = document.getElementById("input").value.split(" ");
  console.log(input)
  num= input.length;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=(f(num)(input));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="abc def ghi">
<button onclick="Permutatino()"> Run </button>
<pre id="output">
```

```javascript
n=>a=>{while(--n&&a[n]>=a[n-1]);if(!n)return a;s=a.slice(--n);for(k=s.length;s[--k]>=a[n];);t=a[n];s[0]=s[k];s[k]=t;return a.slice(0,n).concat(s[0],s.slice(1).reverse())}
```

This code is a sequence of O(n) operations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#fdHBTsQgEAbgu0@hHDZMUshuPBL6IoQDVmhJETYMqwfjs9dWaroxtpfJBD7@geDkFGVrZPv5MfhgKWPxdDIq6lbOlV00CO/oU4Rsyy3HRyNQGo7Bdz8WhEuZjhJ5sLEvg0DF2FgPawGi1AbVWUtU49KNWhbxm7YmnZsIvEuxM4UutsF14wI823eb0VKAr2kmmILlIfXU0WegivSDJw15tW6u5qUjGuBhly2g4h1WczZ8yGragnfYBg6Hbrc6TLt/6UHaPfs/jVxtfrsVU3yKZP04@LOK1@ALJQQApm8)

### Explanation:

```javascript
while(--n>0&&a[n]>=a[n-1]);
```

Find the last location in the array that is not sorted

```javascript
if(!n)return a;
```

If already sorted return

```javascript
s=a.slice(--n);
```

Get everything starting from the point where it was not sorted

```javascript
for(k=s.length;s[--k]>=a[n];);
```

Find the index of the lexicographically closest element to the first element in the unsorted section which is lexicographically less than the first element.

```javascript
t=a[n];s[0]=s[k];s[k]=t;
```

Swap the first element with the found element.

```javascript
return a.slice(0,n).concat(s[0],s.slice(1).reverse())
```

Return the first section of the array + the first element of the second section + the reversed remainder of the second section of the array.

## Time complexity of operations:

slice() O(n)
concat() O(n)
reverse() O(n)
indexOf() O(n) //essentially what the for and while loops were

## O(Nlog(N)) solution 143 - 50% = 71.5 bytes

```javascript
n=>a=>{while(--n&&a[n]>=a[n-1]);if(!n)return a;s=a.slice(--n).sort();t=s.splice(s.indexOf(a[n])-1,1);return a.slice(0,n).concat(t,s.reverse())}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#fZFBasMwEEX3OUWjRZgBW8RkaeQr5ADBC9UZ2QJlFCSlDYSe3bXjFodSezOLz/tvRsionlWlVfX47KwjyHOu9rudPnFdqWHmRY2lNbBlDJRugd90GZWW0dnmSaOMPiTAMqko4/UZR2n5TPejgdGDeZEVWP7Wf6r7bKg2nhudIGVRBvqgEAkQv/ohjt6RdL4FAweEk2g7KzJxJjNM/d6IGnGziI3ABC9gk2eGV7HJNsIL2AysLp2vWrW9vnTF9or9bxNXCpdb0sl6FtIRt6nDP@n4YQmEQMT@Gw)

Comment: Nice solution - takes advantage of the fact that the "right" side of the array will always be in ascending order to start with and need only be reversed. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>55</s> 41 bytes

```
->a{x=a.permutation.sort;x[x.index(a)-1]}
```

#### Explanation:

- `permutation.sort` does exactly what is written on the box
- find the original string
- go back one step, if index is 0, wrap around to -1

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

20 bytes of code, +1 for `-s` flag.

```
(YSSST*PMa^sy@?a-:1)
```

Takes input as a single, space-delimited string on the command line. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@68RGRwcHKIV4JsYV1zpYJ@oa2Wo@f//f93i/4lJyQopqWkKGZkA)

#### Explanation

```
                      a is 1st cmdline arg; s is space (implicit)
                      Part 1:
         a^s           Split a on spaces
       PM              Get all permutations of a
    ST*                Map str() to each of them
                       Because of the -s flag, this joins each sublist on spaces
  SS                   Sort the list using string comparison
 Y                     Yank into the y variable
                      Part 2:
            y@?a       Find index of a in sorted list of permutations y
                -:1    Subtract 1 (using compute-and-assign for lower precedence than @?)
(                  )  Index into part 1 using part 2 (Pip's indexing is cyclical, which
                      takes care of the already-ordered-input case)
                      Print (implicit)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>73</strike>,81 bytes

```python
s=s.split()
import itertools as i
x=sorted(list(i.permutations(s[1:],int(s[0]))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bYpBCoQwEATvecXcjLCI4k3JSxYPWY3sQGJCehb8fXYeYJ26moLrZvKfnb5MRzi7lVPJVYglVMk5gjxUGhwGlMhie/OYmNtB33DYyBDLQwk1/cQL5wsW72nZXnyJrnHrlVaqKt2t/QE)

**Edit:**
Missed the lexicographical sort part of question.

Comment: Your solution should be function or full programm, so you need to specify input. Like `s=input()` or `def f(s)`, etc. And it counts in bytes.

Comment: Also you missed part of question about sorting

Comment: My bad. Didnt notice that lexicographical order part. @DeadPossum Thanks.

Comment: If I use your header, it's supposed to output `abc def hi` instead of the permutations

Comment: Check on try it online ink I've shared along with answer! It does give the permutation sorted lexicographically.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran I mean in the output tab, it should have `abc def hi` instead of the list of permutations that you currently have

Comment: Oh. Just the strings in new line is it?

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
(a=Permutations@Sort@#)[[Max[1,Position[a,#][[1,1]]-1]]]&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a list of strings as input and returns a list of strings as output.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't have built-ins for everything!