# String rotation - output string repeatedly moving first character to the end

Tags: code-golf, string

The challenge here is to take a string and output all its rotations, by repeatedly moving the first character to the end, once per character in the string, ending with the original string:

```
john -> ohnj, hnjo, njoh, john
```

You may also cycle in the other direction, moving characters from the end:

```
john -> njoh, hnjo, ohnj, john
```

You should still output one rotation per letter even if the original word is reached before that:

```
heehee -> eeheeh, eheehe, heehee, eeheeh, eheehe, heehee
```

Character arrays are allowed, as long as the result works as shown above.

Shortest answer wins!

Comment: If a string like `heehee` returns to the original order in fewer cycles than its length, do we stop there? I expect this would make a big difference for many answers.

Comment: May we cycle in the other direction?

Comment: Is the first `john` shown the input or the first "inversion"?

Comment: @xnor, great points!  Thanks so much for the help!  See my edit.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan, the first string is the input, I've edited to clarify.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I edited the question including your clarifications, feel free to change it if it's not what you intended.

Comment: @xnor that looks much clearer than my original post, thanks so much!

Comment: Are we allowed to input/output character arrays? (The distinction can be important in some languages.)

Comment: @LegionMammal978 That's a good point, I hadn't considered that, but yes, that should be fine, as long as a given character array can still be cycled through in the prescribed manner.  I've edited to reflect this distinction.

Comment: Related but different challenge: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/165622/produce-a-list-of-rotonyms-2

Comment: Isn't this just a scrolly text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṙJ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of lists of characters

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzple/w@3R/7/r@SVn5GnBAA)** (footer pretty prints by calling the link and joining with newline characters)

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 27 bytes

```
scanl(\(a:b)_->b++[a])=<<id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCYAgEADQVQ7pQ5EWCG2RjDgt07JLsvm73kvYzq0UjtZxC0hFOomDV0s/eq0nnJU1Jq98YSawUJ9ML3QQQRx3IsFfiAX3xn2o9Qc)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>37</s> 32 bytes

Returns an array of strings.

```javascript
s=>[...s].map(c=>s=s.slice(1)+c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBCoAgEEDRfcdwpUQDHUAvEi1kGlMxR5ro@uY6@Kv3s3@94J3as1Q@qAfbxboNAGSHyzeN1okVkJKQ9GpmNB25CheCwqcOWmWOVRkz/TgSjcboHw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 38 bytes

```python
s=input()
for c in s:s=s[1:]+c;print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v9g2M6@gtERDkystv0ghWSEzT6HYqti2ONrQKlY72bqgKDOvRKH4/3@lrPyMPCUA)

Comment: Python 3 is only 9 more bytes.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Where'd you get 9? [Python 3 - 39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2M6@gtERDkystv0ghWSEzT6HYqti2ONrQKlY72bqgKDOvRKNY8///rPyMPAA "Python 3 – Try It Online") (stdin input without quotes)

Comment: @pizzapants184 I forgot that strings were immutable; you're right; it's only 1 more byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
⍳∘≢⌽¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hv5kcdMx51LnrUs/fQikddTf/THrVNeNTb96hvqqf/o67mQ@uNH7VNBPKCg5yBZIiHZ/D/NAX1rPyMPHUA)

`⍳` the indices

`∘` of

`≢` the tally

`⌽¨` each rotate (to the left)

`⊂` the entire string

Answer (score 5):

## Japt, <s>5</s> 3 bytes

Takes input as a character array, outputs an array of character arrays

```
£=é
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=oz3p&input=WyJqIiwibyIsImgiLCJuIl0KLVE=)

```
£=é     :Implicit input of character array U
£       :Map
  é     :  Rotate U one element to the right
 =      :  Reassign to U for next iteration
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
tf&+)
```

*1 byte saved thanks to @luis!*

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=tf%26%2B%29&inputs=%27John%27&version=20.10.0)!

**Explanation**:

```
    # Implicitly grab input string
t   # Duplicate the input
f   # Create an array [1, ..., N] where N is the number of characters in the input
&+  # Add the transpose of this array to itself to create a 2D array of indices
    #
    #   +   1  2  3  4
    #       ----------
    #   1 | 2  3  4  5
    #   2 | 3  4  5  6
    #   3 | 4  5  6  7
    #   4 | 5  6  7  8
    #
)   # Use this 2D array to index into the original string using periodic indexing
    # Implicitly display the resulting character array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
ā._
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SKNe/P//WfkZeQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
#\|."{]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVmyrp2CgYKVg8F85pkZPqTr2vyaXkp6CepqtnrqCjkKtlUJaMRdXanJGvkKagnpWfkaeOoTn4wYXzUhNBSJ1rv8A)

### Explanation:

```
  |."{    - rotate ( "{ is short for "0 1 - rank 0 1 ) 
      ]   - the input
#\        - lenght of the successive prefixes of the input
```

Comment: Using `"` like that is very clever, and requires dictionary knowledge of the language. Is there also a verb with rank `1 0`?

Comment: @Adám  I think it's `"#:`. I learnt this here from Frownyfrog

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 58 bytes

```r
function(s,`[`=substring)paste0(s[n<-nchar(s):1],s[1,n-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAex/RBYW8Rr5EBEs07bCGq@/fhDlM52w5T4yjNpSkgguW5k2jV3zgu2ikXZLDU2MsV5cEh/GKnFGojQfOUrytoIBtraS0COAf)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 59 bytes

```
,[>,]<[>>[>]+[<]<[<]>-[[>]>[>]<+[<]<[<]>-]>[.>]>[.>]<[<].<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOJ9Ym2s4u2i5WO9oGyLSJtdONBvJAIjYIISBfzw5CgAT0bGL//8/Kz8gDAA)

Outputs each string separated by null bytes.

#### Explanation:

```
,[>,]    # Get input
<[       # Start loop over input
  >>[>]       # Go to end of the string
  +           # Set it to one to mark it
  [<]<[<]>    # Move to the beginning of input
  -[[>]>[>]<+[<]<[<]>-]   # Transfer the first character to the end
  >[.>]>[.>]  # Print the rotated string
  <[<].       # Print a nul byte
<]       # Repeat loop while input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile) 23 bytes

`{:0$(.0@,0@(.0@,#:)9#)}`

Input: a char array followed by its length (stored on stack)

Output: prints rotations of input separated by tab (newline would need an additional character)

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=ezowJCguMEAsMEAoLjBALCM6KTkjKX0KMSQKCiJGb3JXaGlsZSIgMUA_)

## Explanation

```
{          \ define anonymous procedure
:0$        \ store copy of string length at address 0
(.         \ start for-loop, ignore loop-counter
0@,        \ rotate top (string length) stack elements
0@(.0@,#:) \ print string but keep it on the stack
9#         \ print tab
)          \ end outer for-loop
}          \ end procedure
```

Calling the procedure:

```
{:0$(.0@,0@(.0@,#:)9#)} \ procedure
1$                      \ store procedure at address 1
"ForWhile"              \ procedure argument
1@?                     \ call procedure
```

prints:

```
orWhileF    rWhileFo    WhileFor    hileForW    ileForWh    leForWhi    eForWhil    ForWhile
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>35</s> 26 bytes

```
Partition[#,Tr[1^#],1,-1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/T8gsagksyQzPy9aWSekKNowTjlWx1BH1zBW7b@Cg4JzRmJRYnJJalFxtFJWfkaeUmzsfwA)

Takes a list of characters as input.

`Partition` (but not its variant `StringPartition`used below) has an optional fourth argument for treating its input as cyclic (and for specifying how exactly to do so), which makes this solution simpler than the string one - in addition to not having any 15-character built-in functions.

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

```
Rest@StringPartition[#<>#,StringLength@#,1]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/T8otbjEIbgEyEkPSCwqySzJzM@LVraxU9aBCPqk5qWXZDgo6xjGqv1XcFBQysrPyFOK/Q8A)

The same, but takes a string as input.

Turns `"john"` into `"johnjohn"`, then takes all the length-`StringLength["john"]` substrings of this string with offset 1, producing `{"john","ohnj","hnjo","njoh","john"}`, then drops the first of these with `Rest`.

Comment: Since character arrays are allowed, `Rest@Partition[#~Join~#,Length@#,1]&` would be 36 bytes.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Thanks! There's probably also a shorter approach with character arrays, though I haven't thought of anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 13 bytes

```
Rotate#{1:#_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@z8ovySxJFW52tBKOb72v19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajkK0UlZ@Rp6SjoJSRmoqEIFYhkbGJiBaz0pRKTb2PwA)

### Explanation

```
Rotate#{1:#_}
      #          fork(f, g) = ${ f[x, g[x]] }; this forks:
Rotate               rotate's the input by
       {1:#_}        each number from 1 to the length of the input
```

### Alternatives

**15 bytes**: `{_&Rotate!1:#_}`

**16 bytes**: `{Rotate[_,1:#_]}`

**16 bytes**: `Rotate@Rotations`

**16 bytes**: `` Rotate#(1&`:@`#) ``

**17 bytes**: `Rotate#{1+Iota@_}`

**18 bytes**: `` Rotate#(1&`+@Iota) ``

**19 bytes**: `Rotate#(Succ=>Iota)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>54</s> 48 bytes

```python
lambda i:[i[x:]+i[:x]for x in range(1,len(i)+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHTKjozusIqVjsz2qoiNi2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1Vw1AnJzVPI1NT21Az9n9BUWZeiUKahlJWfkaekiYXnJ@RmgpEyCJ@mcmpCs4ZiTlA7empikqa/wE)

Well beaten by [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177231/56555) but posted as an alternative approach anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## C (32-bit), <s>58</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

-1 byte for a nice round number thanks to ceilingcat

```c
i;f(s){for(i=0;i++<printf("%s%.*s\n",s+i,i,s)-2;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcu7CsIwFIDhV4mFQm4VL@Ohu2/goA4hJs2RNJGk1EH00T1ahH4l892g7VECJ5X8fS5cOw38FYK1b1gmjxv2tquZT2nRleFGnUVIOBFo8HErZ6FDaZIOcNfp4lhvwU2n/ACDJUSni@/EArO/aJbDokOLsbMjrnE6@pjfTRDpe5B3bjffQE)

### Degolf

```c
i;           // "Global" i.
f(s){   // s is pointer to string, which conveniently fits in a 32 bit integer.
    for(i=0; // Initialize i.
        // Increment i and take its complement, and add it to the
        // return value of printf(); which just happens to be strlen(s)+1.
        // ~i + strlen(s) + 1 == strlen(s) + 1 - i - 1, so the last printed
        // string is the original string.
        ~++i + printf("%s%.*s\n",s+i,i,s);
        // The printf prints two strings: first until the terminating \0,
        // the second until a \0 or until i chars have been printed. It also
        // prints a linefeed.
}
```

Comment: Suggest `~++i+printf("%s%.*s\n",s+i,i,s)` instead of `i++<printf("%s%.*s\n",s+i,i,s)-2`

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks, as always!

Comment: @ceilingcat You really should be called `flooringcat`.

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P9M6TaNYszotv0gj09bQuqAoM68kTUNJtVhVT6s4Jk9Jp1g7UydTp1jTTls701rTuvY/UAFXbmJmnkZZfmaKJlc1FydQfVZ@Rp6SpjWYnZGaCkQgXu3/f8lpOYnpxf91c42NAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 34 bytes

```cs
x=>x.Select(c=>x=x.Substring(1)+c)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXruPpmleam1qUmJSTChWys1NIU7D9X2FrV6EXnJqTmlyikQxk2wJ5pUkQJRqGmtrJmv@tuQKAvBKNNA2lrPyMPCVNvZB8x6KixEoNTU0kuYzUVCBClf0PAA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>48</s> <s>43</s> 36 bytes

*-5 bytes courtesy of @Bubbler*
*-7 bytes courtesy of @Shaggy

Input is a character array and output is an array of character arrays.

```
s=>s.map(_=>([a,...b]=s,s=[...b,a]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcnBDYAgDEDRu2NwgqjdoCxijBYElSg11rg@cjb5p/cTvST@3q@nz7yEErEI2gEAZISTLj2h1QN1FdyI0gk6SLzneW7JmOI5Cx8BDl511CrxlpUxzY@3EGp1lA8)

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcnBDYAgDEDRu2NwgqjdoCxijBYElSg11rg@cjb5p/cTvST@3q@nz7yEErEI2gEAZISTLj2h1QN1FdyI0gk6SLzneW7JmOI5Cx8BDl511CrxlpUxzY@3EGp1lA8).

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##bclBCoAgEEDRfcdwZWBzg@kiIjGVZWJONNH1TffBX3x4kV6S5T6uZ8i8@rJhERwFTrr0hKO2ZABgdihG0LY15Pq@LJyFk4fEu950AxU5ZFWt@7Hgfa1p@QA)

Comment: @Shaggy Is that a valid byte count and entry? Does `[..."john"]` not count as manipulation of the input string to an array before the function call?

Comment: @guest271314, input is a character and output is an array of character arrays which are permitted by the challenge spec and our I/O defaults.

Comment: @Shaggy Updated. Can you kindly leave your above comment? Or should your comment be included at the answer to avoid confusion? Or is neither necessary?

Comment: Just specify the I/O methods in your solution ([e.g.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177225/58974)) - comments may not last forever.

Comment: @Shaggy Cannot yet explain that for the users here more clearly than you, quoted your language at the answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 39 bytes

```ruby
->s{a=s.chars.to_a;a.map{a.rotate!*''}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OtG2WC85I7GoWK8kPz7ROlEvN7GgOlGvKL8ksSRVUUtdvbb2f4FCWrR6Vn5GnnrsfwA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! It doesn't look like your TIO link corresponds to your answer.  It also seems your answer doesn't fit with our input/output requirements.  You can use either a function or STDIN/STDOUT but we don't allow variable reassignment.

Comment: Thanks Garf. Not sure how I managed to mess both of those up. Should be all good now.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 38 bytes

```
,[>>,]<<<+>[[.>>]<<[<<]>-[+>.>-].<<+>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9rOTifWxsZG2y46Ws/ODsiMtrGJtdON1rbTs9ON1QPJxP7/n5WfkQcA)

Based on the idea of JoKing to use null-characters as space symbols. This code marks the current letters to print and loops until it reaches the left end.

```
,[>>,]<<    input string with empty cells in between
<+>         set first marker
[           main loop
  [.>>]     print remaining characters
  <<[<<]    return to start
  >-[+>.>-] print until marker (remove marker)
  .         print null
  <<+       set new marker
  >         restart loop with next character to the left
]           stop if there's no character to the left
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$13\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 10.701 bytes

```
$#GLxWxO'+]xq
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIkI0dMeFd4TycrXXhxIiwiam9obiJd)

This is so long

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 105 bytes

```go
func f(s[]rune)(o[][]rune){for i:=0;i<len(s);i++{o=append([][]rune{append(s[i:],s[:i]...)},o...)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY_BTsQgEIbP8hSEE2Sx8WhY-w7em8ZgF7q4W2hm6In0Sbw0Jj6EV9_Ct5EtrRKSmUn--b_53z_6sHyNurvo3tBBO0_cMAaIFbNDZJ9TtPePP85OvqOWY9PC5I3goWm3NtkA1Kn64eiersZzFEd3OKRQ63E0_sR3YdpmbJxqJTbKtVVViVmGtRAwcQI_b8DvFXjhgH8gjrnHCM73BfoiQdWgfb4bMCHuRERZZBzEvzEhq-UtIRc0EUSqaro7JvYWzp5Jys7G5H_r9Gt3MpbNpMBWfcHl3UTunvNivObEMh9qeTkz58-PzGRLsiyl_gI)

Without the requirement of the original being at the end, this saves 13 bytes:

#### 92 bytes

```go
func f(s[]rune)(o[][]rune){for i:=0;i<len(s);i++{o=append(o,append(s[i:],s[:i]...))}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9BbsMgEEXX5RSIFSjU6rIi9R2yd62KOuDQxGDN4BXySbqxKvUQ3fYWvU2JcaqikfiLmf_-f__ow_I16u6se0MH7TxxwxggVswOkX1O0d4__jzbyXfUcmxamLwRPDTtJpMNQJ2qH_bu6WI8R7F3u10KtR5H4488yE1g41QrsVGurapKiJmAiRP4eWN8r4wzB_zz5pg1RnC-L5wXCaoG7XNUwIR4gyDKssbhnzEhq-W1FBc0EUSqanpzTOwtnDyTlJ2MyXNV-rU7GstmUmDrfsHl20TuDvkwXnJJmYNaXmLmyvmRmWxNlqX8vw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 bytes

```
:(m
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3A%28m&i=john%0Aheehee&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 31 bytes

```julia
!s=(r=keys(s)).|>i->(s*s)[i.+r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HYVqPINju1slijWFNTr8YuU9dOo1irWDM6U0@7KPa/Q3FGfrmColJWfkaeEheMl5GaCkRK/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 26 bytes

```ruby
$_.scan(/./){puts$'+$`+$&}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5ejlLsgqWlJWm6FrtU4vWKkxPzNPT19DWrC0pLilXUtVUStFXUaiEKoOoWLMnKz8iDsAE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
(Ǔ…
```

#### Explanation:

```
(   # For each char in the input
 Ǔ  # Rotate left
  … # Print without popping
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIox5PigKYiLCIiLCJqb2huIl0=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ż€Ỵ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK47uedS05uHuLUuKk5KLoYILlmWkpgIRhAcA)

##### Explanation

```python
ż€Ỵ  # Implicit input
ż    # Push the length range
 €   # For each number in this range:
  Ỵ  #  Rotate the input left that many times
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 30 bytes

```arturo
$->s[0-1map s=>[rotate s<=1+]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?rEtDLt)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

Another JS answer, which doesn't beat any of the previous JS ones.
Input is an array of characters (as seen in other answers), and output is an array of strings.
Rotates the string the inverted way, as allowed by OP.

```javascript
s=>[...s].map(_=>[...s]=s.pop()+s.join``)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5BCsIwEEX3niLMKsGYAwjRvQtduBSxpU5tSk1CJ4oewJ1H0Mt5kRobuxGEgc/Pf/MzdX7OqWiNDxPr9tiVuiM92yilaKuOuee7wWlS3nkuxqRqZ2yWiS4nwjZobqw/BYkXj0XAvWyRTk3Qi/VqqSi0xh5MeeVlwoQQelY4S65B1bgD519c66FgDq/HjcEUXs87AzFOgBiN0n@csc9FULvKwpZJlm3ARgMSqqhRYlBHSUDGmPjZrBDjDLvY28j3r31NyuX/qG/t3g)

---

Different approach that swaps each character with their corresponding one, obtained via calculation of its index (correct rotation direction, **58 bytes**) :

```javascript
s=>s.map((_,i)=>s.map((_,j)=>s[(i+j+1)%s.length]).join``)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BasMwDIbvfQojKFjEM@w68HbfoT3sGMoSUiWxyewQuWV7gN32CNvL9UUyJ15hDAZCv3706ZerzzU3kx3jjQ9Hmlszs7ln/VKPUj4ri7@MW0wpbeGKW9yyHsh3sT@gdsH6qsK5ZqYpGmn9eIqKXkdqIh3VRHwaonl82u80x8n6zrZvss0YYkptgucwkB5CJ@UPbsw14AEun@8C7uDy9SEAiwzgZpP/SSFKrTW40Hs4CCWqEtLoQEHqIUnqfZIMVELgn8ueKNX1djULvyotMXmv/l@tqfM3)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 8 bytes

```
ýñx$pÙñd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DewxsrVAoOzzy8MeX/f6/8jDwA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: fdf1 7824 70d9 f164                      ..x$p..d
```

Comment: `ýñx$pÙñd` gives 8 by removing the need to `H` https://tio.run/##K/v///DewxsrVAoOzzy8MeX/f6/8jDwA

Comment: @Cowsquack Even better: `ý<M-->ñx$pÙ`

Comment: Doesn't that repeat the last line?

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 80 <s>91</s> bytes

```
proc P s {time {puts [set s [string ra $s 1 e][string in $s 0]]} [string le $s]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pco7CsAgFETR3lVMkQUk@7CwDxYij8TgD32pxLUbUyQwcOEwbP0YuSQLhYrGLhBavrlir8R4w8XFA8VgqdhA@hMXX1m17v/J0yTdhw8mQ6KJK51RnERzoqMpLLKPBw)

Comment: Reassign text at each time saves some bytes
`proc R t {time {puts [set t [string ra $t 1 end][string in $t 0]]} [string len $t]}`

Comment: Got it down to 80 bytes, thanks to @david

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⮌Ｅθ⭆θ§θ⁻μκ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCMotSy1qDhVwzexQKNQRyG4BCiaDuU4lnjmpaRWgJi@mXmlxRq5OgrZmmBg/f9/Vn5G3n/dshwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ         Input string
 Ｅ         Map over characters
    θ       Input string
   ⭆        Map over characters and join
      θ     Input string
     §      Circularly indexed by
       ⁻    Difference between
        μ   Inner index
         κ  Outer index
⮌           Reversed
            Implicitly print each string on its own line
```

To rotate in the opposite direction, replace `Minus` with `Plus`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>49</strike> 43 bytes

```
func[s][forall s[print move head s tail s]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBCcAgDEDRu1MEx@gYvYYcpEnQoqao7fqp8A8P/hD2Uxgp6OH69gsnodpItcLEZ5S@oNknkCUxTFip7EHkCvG23GPYyCK76D8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 32 bytes

```
{m:ex/^(.*)(.+)$/».&{[R~] @$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OtcqtUI/TkNPS1NDT1tTRf/Qbj216uigulgFB5X42tr/xYmVCkoq8Qq2dgrVaQpAISWFtPwiBZus/Iw8hYzUVCCys/4PAA)

`m:ex/^(.*)(.+)$/` `ex`haustively `m`atches the given regex, splitting the input string at every possible place, except that the second substring must have at least one character--that prevents the input string from showing up twice in the output.  Then each of the resulting `Match` objects' capture groups are reduced (`[]`) to a single string with `R~`, the reversed string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 4 bytes

```
L:{"
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/Hqlrp////Sl75GXlKAA)**

```
L:    \ Length of the string times do:
  {   \    Cyclically shift left once
   "  \    Print
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 44 bytes

```powershell
($s=$args|% t*y)|%{$h,$t=$s;-join($s=$t+$h)}
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

($s=$args|% t*y)|%{$h,$t=$s;-join($s=$t+$h)}

}

@(
    ,('john', 'ohnj', 'hnjo', 'njoh', 'john')
    ,('heehee', 'eeheeh', 'eheehe', 'heehee', 'eeheeh', 'eheehe', 'heehee')
) | % {
    $s,$expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$result"-eq"$expected"
    $result
}
```

output:

```powershell
True
ohnj
hnjo
njoh
john
True
eeheeh
eheehe
heehee
eeheeh
eheehe
heehee
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pepe](//github.com/Soaku/Pepe), <s>64</s> 52 bytes

```
rEEEEeREEeRREeeeREEReREEEeeReReeeReeERREeeerEEEEERee
```

[Try it online!](https://soaku.github.io/Pepe/#-gT-!dF.-d.HJ-!d-i/) Uses newlines for separation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 85 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=s.length();i-->0;)System.out.println(s.substring(i)+s.substring(0,i));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU49b4MwEN35FScm3AQrc9ywdO6UsergEANHwUa@c6Qq4rdTvkQrFcvW6X3c86v1Q6f1/WvAtnOeoR6xDIyNfFHRP64INmd0dlck9ka3k5Q3mgjeNVp4RgBduDWYA7HmcTwc3qEdteTKHm358QnalyRmK8CbsxRa418XNYMCLgOl2bNwPkHLgBeSjbElV4lQmKbZSYnrN7FppQssu3GLG5uQpHCjOSNBcfgLT0cUQvWDmj/cWrAhJrisPaYT166y8fEXV8aMN16JfgmYii0hc8R5CRJbzk65yQEHiM8QC7XaCqnz3HQ8ixu7s7xqfTS9fvgB)

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 82 bytes

```
	S =INPUT
T	X =X + 1
	S LEN(1) . L REM . R
	OUTPUT =S =R L LE(X,SIZE(S))	:S(T)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYs9C4AgFABn/RVvfFIEQlPg1oMM0/ADpLE5cuj/Y286OO6@t93tmXsXCYz1Z8kyiwqmwgBasnTkUSuYwEGkgxmlCCVzCIaXyN4R1jHZizApJZaEWUnya@972PwP)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 5 bytes

```
hÅ╫o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/jcOujqavzrf//V/fKz8hTBwA)

### Explanation

```
h       length of array/string without popping
 Å      start block of length 2
  ╫     left-rotate bits in int, list/str
   o    print TOS without popping
    ;   discard TOS
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 61 bytes

```lua
function(s)for i=1,#s do print(s:sub(i+1)..s:sub(1,i))end end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/J9m@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NYMy2/SCHT1lBHuVghJV@hoCgzr0Sj2Kq4NEkjU9tQU08PwjbUydTUTM1LUQDi/xBFaQrqXvkZeeqa/wE)

Split string at successive indices from one to the length of the string (one-based indexing), concatenate the pieces in the reverse order, print.

Answer (score 1):

## perl 5, 18 (-n) bytes

Thanks to Xcali

```
s/./say$',$`,$&/ge
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0@/OLFSRV1HJUFHRU0/PfX//6z8jLx/@QUlmfl5xf918/7r@prqGRgaAAA)

Original answer (23 bytes)

```
/^.+?(?{say$'.$&})(?!)/
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18/Tk/bXsO@ujixUkVdT0WtVlPDXlFT////rPyMvH/5BSWZ@XnF/3Xz/uv6muoZGBoAAA)

Comment: [18 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0@/OLFSRV1HJUFHRU0/PfX//6z8jLx/@QUlmfl5xf918/7r@prqGRgaAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 88 bytes

```
(lambda(x)(loop for s from 1 to(length x)do(format t"~a~a "(subseq x s)(subseq x 0 s))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYkxDoAgEAS/sqE6On3SqSga4JTDhIqvI51TzWTWcOrdqVPguGxM1VIQubFLhmLPEjGjCAWXjuJR7SY0XuSCYho3hiF9F3UPKtT@Po0adHOJT8b2Dw)

Answer (score 1):

### [MBASIC](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual), <s>69</s> 66 bytes

-3 bytes, thanks to Ørjan Johansen

```
1 INPUT S$:L=LEN(S$):FOR I=1 TO L:S$=MID$(S$+S$,2,L):PRINT S$:NEXT
```

Comment: I suspect you can shorten that to `1 INPUT S$:L=LEN(S$):FOR I=1 TO L:S$=MID$(S$+S$,2,L):PRINT S$:NEXT`.

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen Very nice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 25 bytes

```factor
[ all-rotations reverse ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcoxDsIwDAXQvaf4yk4PAAsbYmFBTIjBRB81EDnFdhGcPrAhvfHdJEezfjruD7s1nM@Fmukj32HieNCUFbMx4jNb0fgfbIYh3dukCWkif1I/Q2pdWQuJ0tRhfNGcuPRr2WJ05Eqx/gU)

```
               ! "john"
all-rotations  ! { "john" "ohnj" "hnjo" "njoh" }
reverse        ! { "njoh" "hnjo" "ohnj" "john" }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
żvǓ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwixbx2x5MiLCIiLCJKb2huIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 bytes

```apl
{(↓,↑)∘⍵¨⍳≢⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v1rjUdtknUdtEzUfdcx41Lv10IpHvZsfdS4CMmv/pz1qm/Cot@9R31RP/0ddzYfWGwMVAnnBQc5AMsTDM/h/moJ6Vn5GnjoA)

Over twice as long as the [other](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177223/107299) APL answer, but uses a different more literal tactic. Test harness stolen from that answer.

```apl
{(↓,↑)∘⍵¨⍳≢⍵}
{           } ⍝ Define function
         ⍳≢   ⍝ Indexes of
           ⍵  ⍝ The input
        ¨     ⍝ For each item in ^
 (   )        ⍝ Apply the following function:
  ↓              ⍝ Drop n elements
    ↑            ⍝ Take n elements
   ,             ⍝ Concatenate the 2 above results
      ∘⍵      ⍝ Bind the right input of the above function to the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```
Listen to S
X's 0
While S at X
Cut S
Rock roll S in S
Join S
Say S
Let X be+1
```

[Try it](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 52 bytes

```lua
s=...for i=1,#s do s=s:sub(2)..s:sub(1,1)print(s)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZPTy8tv0gh09ZQR7lYISVfodi22Kq4NEnDSFNPD8Iy1DHULCjKzCvRKNZMzUv5//9/Vn5GHgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
s=>[...s].map(_=>s=s.slice(1)+_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBCoAgEEDRfcdwpUQDHUAvEiFiYyrmSBNd31wHf/V@dq9jf6f2LJUO7EF31mYDAN7hck1abVgzcEke5apmq7qnylQQCp0ySJEpVqHU9OOIOBqjfw)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(_=>s=[...s.slice(1),_])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1q5YLzexQCMeyLCN1tPTK9YrzslMTtUw1NSJj9X8n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaYBUqCUlZ@RpxSrqcmFRS4jNRWIQLL/AQ)

[Found similarity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/177285/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 3 bytes

```
x→Ř
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FssqHrVNOjpjSXFScjFUaMF6paz8jDwlLqWM1FQgUoIIAwA)

```
x       Enumerate; push [0, 1, ..., len(input) - 1]
 →      Increment
  Ř     Rotate right by that amount (automatically vectorized)
```

Unfortunately `x` is 0-indexed, so we have to increment it before rotating.

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) - 179 bytes

```rkt
#!racket
(let([s(read-line)][a string-append])(let g([r s][i(string-length s)])(display(a r(if(= i 0)""" -> ")))(if(= i 0)(void)(g(a(substring r 1)(~a(string-ref r 0)))(- i 1)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw7DsIwEER7TrExzW5hKTkA1NzBSrHgxVhYJlobpDRc3SR8xFSj@Tzl01Vqa9tO326DSSq6girsbYpZaHQMpWrMwfI0SfYjrSMI6BTK6CJ@2yQ51AsUWgY@linxjAyK8Yw7iNCTMQbsHgwR/UN83KInDMhY7scPChQGwif/yCrnJerXn11OA61q7SAzdy8)

---

### Explanation

On line one we have the required language expression. Yesterday, I learnt that `#![language]` is short for `#lang [language]`, but it is discouraged in normal programs.

On line two, we define an immediately invoked function using `let`. The parent `let` receives a line of input from the user and passes it to it's child `let` called `g`. The child `let` acts as a recursive loop that uses the length of the parent string as an iterator. The first `if` check is in charge of pretty printing the rotated string. (While it would save some bytes to remove it, I like the way it looks.) The second check is used to determine whether the string should be rotated again or if the program should end.

To rotate the string, we split the string at index 1 and append the first character to the end of the string.

```rkt
#lang racket

(let ([str (read-line)] [str-app string-append])
  (let loop ([rotated str] [idx (string-length str)])
    (display (str-app rotated (if (= idx 0) "" " -> ")))
    (if (= idx 0)
      (void)
      (loop (str-app (substring rotated 1)
                     (~a (string-ref rotated 0)))
            (- idx 1)))))
```

---

### Output (Input: `Heya!`)

```
Heya! -> eya!H -> ya!He -> a!Hey -> !Heya -> Heya!
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 5.9, <s>65</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```swift
var s="",r={s=$0
s.map{$0
s+=[s.removeFirst()]
print(s)}}
```

`r(_:)` is the closure to call.

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 23 bytes

```ruby
:*%[:& &:rotate,:+@|:+]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboW2620VKOt1BTUrIrySxJLUnWstB1qrLRjIbI3tQsU3KKj7bN07PN17DN07PNiY7kgQkBOKhhBGbFQLQsWQGgA)

### Explanation

```
:* % [:& & :rotate, :+@ | :+]
                    :+@ | :+   # Range 1..(input length)
:* % [            ,         ]  # Map with...
      :& & :rotate             #   Rotate input chars
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 7 bytes

```
⇌≡↻⇡⊃⧻¤
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4oeM4omh4oa74oeh4oqD4qe7wqQKCkYgImpvaG4iCg==)

If it is allowed to start with the input rather than end with it, then remove the reverse for -1 byte.

```
⇌≡↻⇡⊃⧻¤
    ⊃⧻¤  # fix the input and get its length
   ⇡     # range
 ≡↻      # rotate input by each number in the range
⇌        # reverse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
l≥ℕ₁;?↺₍
```

Generator solution: takes a string as input, outputs one rotation at a time when called repeatedly. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/qG3Do6bGh7s6H3Ut/Z/zqHPpo5apQAFr@0dtux419f7/r1RcUpSZl670PwIA)

#### Explanation

```
l≥ℕ₁;?↺₍
l          Length of input string
 ≥         Get a number less than or equal to that
  ℕ₁       which is also an integer greater than or equal to 1
    ;?     Put it in a list with the input string
      ↺₍   Rotate the latter the former number of times
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 40 bytes

```
For(I,1,length(Ans)-1
sub(Ans,2,length(Ans)-1)+sub(Ans,1,1
Disp Ans
End
Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`. Rotates to the left.

Comment: Wouldn't it be shorter to store `length(Ans)-1` in a variable?

Comment: @MarcMush It wouldn't because you would have to store the input in a string variable.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
1..$s.Length|%{$s=$s[1..$s.Length]+$s[0]-join'';$s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmfll@UmpicoaFSrJCZp6CSWJRerFn931BPT6VYzyc1L70ko0a1WqXYVqU4GlkwVhsoYBCrm5Wfmaeubq1SXPu/9v9/paz8jDwlBaWM1FQgUgIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
VSlQ+>QN<QN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyw4J1DbLtDPJtDv/3@lrPyMPCUA)

Pretty much just a port of my Python answer

**Explanation**

```
==================================================
assign('Q',eval_input())
for N in num_to_range(Psorted(Plen(Q))):
 imp_print(plus(gt(Q,N),lt(Q,N)))
==================================================

V                    # for N in 
 S                   # 1-indexed range
  lQ                 # length of evaluated input
    +                # concatanate
     >QN             # all characters after index N in Q (Q[N:])
        <QN          # and all characters before index N in Q (Q[:N])
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 78 bytes

```
proc R t {time {puts [set t [regsub -all (.?)(.*) $t {\2\1}]]} [string le $t]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAgGAbQq3xDgwUJdYHu4JoOJWKFpejvJJ7dXB@PtGstRK8hQCh0vwYlZErYk6FOezQ25RPz4RwY30bGpxFDv3KVS1Wq9knx/iyc6a5qE3j89bUf)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 36 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy by using `shift()` instead of `splice()`.*

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>a.push(a.shift())&&a+"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbBDYAgDADAXXiQNsZugAO4gvHRIAgGKRE0bo/xXnfww9VesbQxy@a6N53NxHRygfdPuWsAphqib4CoNQ9KYbeSqyRHSXbwsBCRmiVktSL2Dw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 20 bytes

```perl6
{.rotate(all 1..$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1qvKL8ksSRVIzEnR8FQT08lXrP2f1p@kYJNVn5GnkJGaioQKQQEOLvbKVRzKSgoFCdWKqRp6CXn5ybp@WQWl2jqZeVn5nHV/gcA)

Anonymous code block that has input/output as a list of characters. The output is a Junction object that contains all the rotated arrays. I'm not sure how legal this is, since extracting values from a Junction is [not normal](https://docs.perl6.org/language/faq#index-entry-Junction_%28FAQ%29).

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                  }   # Anonymous codeblock
 .rotate(         )    # Rotate the input list
         all 1..$_     # By all of the range 1 to length of the input array
                          # all creates a junction of values
                          # And it runs the function on each value
```

The `all` can be replaced by any of `any`, `one`, `[&]`, `[|]`, `[^]`.

If the Junction isn't allowed, here's an alternate solution for 22 bytes:

```perl6
{.&{.rotate(++$)xx$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pPrVqvKL8ksSRVQ1tbRbOiQiW@tvZ/Wn6Rgk1WfkaeQkZqKhApBAQ4u9spVHMpKCgUJ1YqpGnoJefnJun5ZBaXaOrlJhZoaOll5WfmaXLV/gcA)

There's probably a better way to reset the anonymous variable `++$` than by wrapping the code in another code block...

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```c
i;f(int*a){for(i=0;a[i++];printf("%S%.*S ",a+i,i,a));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P9M6TSMzr0QrUbM6Lb9II9PWwDoxOlNbO9a6oAgonqahpBqsqqcVrKCkk6idqZOpk6ipaV37HyilkJuYmaehWc3Fmabho5SVn5GnpGnNVfsfAA)

Takes input as a wide string.

Comment: Loop until `a[i++]` to save 7 bytes.

Comment: Oh, no `char*`. You'd still save bytes, though (just make `i` global and `f(char*a)`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 64 bytes

```clj
(fn[w](take(count w)(rest(iterate #(str(subs % 1)(first %))w))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAwDATArwRF2Bx9j3hQidgqqSQpfX51TnM8JVeTjteSxqOEjlOXtiK2W3CUqkGNYeKBFGJbCI3wMHjdnSaaGWcyD5qYG//6kMulw58P)

See the pre-golfed code below for an explanation. Returns a (lazy) list of strings.

```clj
(defn cycle-word [word]
  (->> ; Take the word
       word

       ; Create an infinite list of iterations of strings where
       ;   the first character is moved to the end of the subs(tring)
       (iterate #(str (subs % 1) (first %)))

       ; Drop the first result since we don't want it to start with the original word
       (rest)

       ; Then take as many iterations from the infinite list as the word has characters
       (take (count word))))

(cycle-word "john")
=> ("ohnj" "hnjo" "njoh" "john")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
_.e.>Qk
```

Accepts input as a string or as a list of characters, output is a list of the same. Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_.e.%3EQk&input=%22abcde%22&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.chars.map{s=s[1..-1]+s[0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvOSOxqFgvN7Gguti2ONpQT0/XMFa7ONogtrb2f4FCWrRSVn5GnlLsfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 59 bytes

```
>iu0l:1-}[{ R{:0=1\
/:$ak$0l1-[{U$:/?-/
\}?*2=0:-1{]{~ /;$~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98us9Qgx8pQtza6WiGo2srA1jCGS99KJTFbxSDHUDe6OlTFSt9eV58rptZey8jWwErXsDq2uk5B31ql7v9/n/y89BgF58QSAA)

Can handle inputs up to 8 characters (spaces need to be escaped, however).

Essentially just a bunch of stack manipulation, with integer 0 denoting the end of the stack and the original length used as a counter held at the end.

Without using the stack-of-stacks commands `[` and `]` the solution is slightly larger (63 bytes) but can handle strings up to 16 characters:

```
>iu0l1-}l1-sRl1-s:0 \
/s:$ak$0l1-sU$:/?-1=/
\-1l}?*5=0:-1{~/;${
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98us9Qgx1C3FoiLg0CElYFCDJd@sZVKYrYKSKY4VMVK317X0FafK0bXMKfWXsvU1sBK17C6Tt9apfr/f6/8jLwYBefEopLUIgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Reticular](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/reticular), <s>56</s> 38 bytes

```
iSL:%=@qB[:%`@d]:%`*[[o]:%`1-*p$]:%`*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otyUwuzUks@v8/M9jHStXWodAp2ko1wSElFkhqRUfng2hDXa0CFbCA9f//XvkZeSAMAA)

### Explanation with input "Hee"

```
iS                # Read input string and put its chars into an array
L:%=              # Get length of string and save it as `%`
@qB               # Reverse array and push its items to the stack
                   Stack: [H, e, e]
[:%`@d]:%`*       # Duplicates the top length(str) items in the stack
                   a total of length(str) number of times
                   Stack before: [H, e, e]
                   Stack after: [H, e, e, H, e, e, H, e, e, H, e, e]
[[o]:%`1-*p$]:%`* # Output the top length(str) items from the stack
                    with a trailing newline, and then
                    pop the next item in the stack.
                    Iterate this `%` number of times
                    Stack before: [H, e, e, H, e, e, H, e, e, H, e, e]

                    Stack after 1st iteration: [e, e, H, e, e, H, e, e]
                    Output: Hee
                    Stack after 2nd iteration: [e, H, e, e]
                    Output: Hee
                            eeH
                    Stack after 3rd iteration: []
                    Output: Hee
                            eeH
                            eHe

;                 # Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
for($s=$argv[1];$x++<strlen($s);)echo$s=substr($s,1).$s[0]," ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCoAgEEDRq0i4SJKwtUUHCYmKKYPIYbTo9tPAXz0@RuR@xIgKiBLNBJionPdRO@N5T1TrPOiFjnfqgtdf0/S50AW3uPEGtphkyM8qKmQ70@o8uWArVXlmjgDSDw)

### Output

```php
$php strrot.php john
ohnj hnjo njoh john

$php strrot.php heehee
eeheeh eheehe heehee eeheeh eheehe heehee
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>103</s>, 79 bytes

Without LINQ.

EDIT:  ASCII-only golfing -24 bytes with a better use of a for loop and substring return!

```cs
p=>{var s="";for(int j=0;j++<p.Length;s+=p+" ")p=p.Substring(1)+p[0];return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BC8IgGEDv/QrxpFiyzs5dgk4FwQ4dosPmrDmWip8OYuy322DBg3d6PAUH5YLOamwA0G32qR2NQhCbuGpypkPXxlhC5139hag//JysKiEGY9/7TVUns5fVPDUBgcRYvFwgxkY0yEIMjJWeX7R9x14Ak55hhKmXntep3XpypMw/iqcIOqZgEYgli//t5Cy4UfN7MFGTjuBe6xVMqViW/AM)

Comment: [79](https://tio.run/##LY1BC8IgGEDv/QrxpFiyzs5dgk4FwQ4dosPmrDmWip8OYuy322DBg3d6PAUH5YLOamwA0G32qR2NQhCbuGpypkPXxlhC5139hag//JysKiEGY9/7TVUns5fVPDUBgcRYvFwgxkY0yEIMjJWeX7R9x14Ak55hhKmXntep3XpypMw/iqcIOqZgEYgli//t5Cy4UfN7MFGTjuBe6xVMqViW/AM)

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 11 bytes

```
=A#|LA)&_lZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/39ZRucbHUVMtPifq//@s/Iw8AA)

### Explanation

```
=A#|LA)&_lZ

=A              first term in sequence is the input
  #|LA)         add second input n: length of input
       &        output first n terms in sequence
                each term equals:
        _l                        unary rotate left of 
          Z                                            previous term
```

Replace `_l` with `_r` to rotate right instead of left.