# Give me the first day of next month

Tags: code-golf, date

Simple question!

Given a string that contains a date in ISO8601 format, print the first of the next month in ISO8601 format.

Example inputs:

`2018-05-06`

`2019-12-20`

Their respective outputs:

`2018-06-01`

`2020-01-01`

The rules:

- Imports are free and don't count towards your score.
- The date will be stored in a string called `s`.
- The solution with the least characters, wins

Comment: Please avoid creating new tags unless they're really missing. We already have [`date`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) and [`parsing`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing). The `beginner` tag is an interesting idea, but I think that should be discussed in meta. On the other hand, you _must_ include a tag telling what's the winning criterion. Is this [`code-golf`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)?

Comment: I suggest removing *The date will be stored in a string called `s`.* and leave it up to the answerers to use any of the default I/O methods. Btw, reading from a pre-defined variable is not among those defaults. Also, not all languages have strings, and not all languages have variables.

Comment: Do you mean the output should be stored in `s`, or that the input would be stored in `s`?

Comment: @Arnauld There was [discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/42963) around that topic (a "beginner" or "easy" tag) quite a while ago with no clear consensus. IMO that's still the case because it's very subjective.

Comment: Within a day of posting this, 5 people flocked to close it as off-topic because it didn't contain an objective primary winning criterion. I thought "the least characters" was the default winning criterion? Isn't it _quite_ petty to shut this down like that?

Comment: I'd say, the newly-added `The solution with the least characters, wins` could count as the winning criteria, but we prefer not to specify a variable that the input/output have to be stored inside

Comment: Will year always in 0001 ~ 9998? If not so, please include testcases "-0001-01-01", "9999-12-31", "+10000-01-01" ect.

Comment: Also, Year in 0001 ~ 0999 may cause some solutions fail: "0100-12-01". This may be exclude from requirement or add to testcase.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>67</s>, <s>57</s>, 56 bytes

-10 thanks to Arnauld,
-1 joining template string and ternary

```
s=>([a,b]=s.split`-`,+a+!(b%=12))+`-${b++<9?'0'+b:b}-01`
```

Test cases:

```js
f=s=>([a,b]=s.split`-`,+a+!(b%=12))+`-${b++<9?'0'+b:b}-01`

console.log(f('2018-12-20'))
console.log(f('2019-05-06'))
```

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc7RCoIwFIDh@94iMLahR85ZGBqtHiSCbaZiDCdNuhF79eV9eP3xw/8yHxPqdz9OMPhnE1sVg7ryu8nsQ4U8jK6fNOgsNeme24MiKVINyWwv1Q3PjC3JDF@7AJIWsfZD8K7Jne94y5lEKgELwBMTYvePFZAEiVuIJVCxiRUcN0ui9WfF@AM) (without assuming that the input is stored in _s_, as this unusual requirement will hopefully be removed)

Comment: I never knew you could do that with split, thanks for the input. Might I also ask what's happening with the -~b part? @Arnauld

Comment: `-~b` is `-(-b-1)` and works on non-numeric values. But since `b` is already coerced to a number by the modulo, you can actually just use `b+1` here.

Comment: @Kobe `-~b` is basically `b+1` (or actually `-(-b-1)`). It can be useful to skip parenthesis sometimes, although it's not really necessary in this case, so you could change it to `b+1` being more readable if you'd prefer. [Relevant tip.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67630/52210) You might also find [Tips for golfing in JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) and [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) interesting to read through. Welcome to CGCC!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks for the comment and links, I'll definitely take a look at those soon :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>31</s>, 24 bytes

7 bytes saved thanks to @manatwork and @nwellnhof

```bash
date -d${1%??}1month +%F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcexCoAgFAXQva@4Q03xQIWiaGjrJ6TBeA8MLKGEhurbre2cxZ0@X34NgkMcI@B5YC3KgHkeOOKUBKL/mV0SEJe3rsbx1Vvck0ddTZnjLtko3ZFqSLXFz560IaM@)

Comment: Wow! `date`'s parsing ability keeps amazing me. BTW, I think you can skip the “0”.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) 49 bytes

```
d=Date.parse(s);print Date.new(d.year,d.mon,1)>>1
```

[Online repl](https://repl.it/repls/GuiltyAmazingPercent)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net), 57 bytes

```
[$y,$m]=explode('-', $s);$m=++$m%13?:!!++$y;$d="$y-$m-1";
```

Test cases:

```
<?php
function next_month($s) {
    [$y,$m]=explode('-', $s);
    $m=++$m%13?:!!++$y;
    return "$y-$m-1";
}

$s = "2018-05-06";
echo next_month($s); // Gives 2018-6-1

$s = "2019-12-20";
echo next_month($s); // Gives 2020-1-1
```

Comment: Consider using [Try it online!](https://tio.run/#php "PHP – Try It Online") to demonstrate your code.

Comment: ISO8601 requires `Each date and time value has a fixed number of digits that must be padded with leading zeros`, meaning output of `2018-6-1` or `2020-1-1` is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 33 bytes

```
T`9d`d`.9*(-12)?-..$
-23|-..$
-01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyTBMiUhJUHPUktD19BI015XT0@FS9fIuAbCMDD8/9/IwNBC18BU18CMC8i0BCrTNTIAAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
T`9d`d`
```

Increment with wrap-around...

```
.9*(-12)?-..$
```

... the last non-`9` digit, plus trailing `9`s, in either the year or the month, depending on whether the month is `12`. (Digits in the following date parts also get incremented.)

```
-23|-..$
-01
```

Replace the day with `01`. Also, if the month was `12` before, it will be `23` now, and also needs to be reset to `01`.

Answer (score 0):

## Red, 39 bytes

```
t: load s
t/month: t/month + t/day: 1
t
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.6.9, 73 characters

```
from datetime import *; from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as r; 
(datetime(*map(int, s.split('-')), 1) + r(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-01')
```

Your rules say that imports don't count, so I didn't count them.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Since imports don't count you can `from datetime import datetime as d` to save a few bytes. Also, you can remove

Comment: Whoops, accidentally hit enter. Your program does not appear to output anything, so you would need a `print` statement. To catch this, I suggest using TIO, such as by adding a link: [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VY3NCsIwEITvPkUu0o02JVEUofRBPAaS0oX8sdkKPn2sBxVvM8P3MeXJS07nNlOOwln2jNELjCUT/7qtwo3iy6yMYSAfLOPDOx/Yfoz/cdNo3NUJU1kZZCuEiQEcHKItsOW@DrUEZOhUJ2Vv5JEg5sRLnYyUQ2Wa3//Q7e9qH5U2G9XaSZub0helry8). (I incorporated a couple more suggestions to shorten it to 69 bytes).