# How happy is this emoticon?

Tags: code-golf, string

In this challenge, submissions will be programs or function which, when given an emoticon such as `:-)`, `:(`, or `:D`, will rate their happiness from 0 to 3.

An emoticon will be one of the following:

- `:(`: 0
- `:|`: 1
- `:)`: 2
- `:D`: 3

Emoticons may also have noses (a `-` after the `:`).

Test cases:

```
:(  -> 0
:-| -> 1
:D  -> 3
:-) -> 2
:|  -> 1
```

This is a code golf challenge, shortest answer per language wins.

Comment: What about `(:`?

Comment: @anatolyg I figured having to handle reversed strings as well would make the challenge too difficult

Comment: @anatolyg Don't forget ☺and ☻ either

Comment: @anatolyg What about `D:`?

Comment: or `:-{D` (someone with a mustache) or `:-{D>` (someone with a mustache and goatee) or `:-{D}` (someone with a mustache and beard).  For a full list see http://marshall.freeshell.org/smileys.html

Comment: It would be cool to see a solution that looked like a smiley ...

Comment: Only 8 possible inputs?

Comment: @Iamkindofalanguagedev Yes

Answer (score 18):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 26 bytes

```python
lambda s:ord(s[-1])*2%19%4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRodgqvyhFozha1zBWU8tI1dBS1eR/am5@SWZyfl4xUGE0l4KCkpWuhpIOmFEDpTWhtK6LElcsF1dafpFCqkJmngJcqxVQuqAoM69EI00jVVPzPwA)

$$ f(x) = (2x \bmod 19) \bmod 4 $$

Comment: You can save 1 character by using the formula in the Ruby solution below : https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202907/61997

Comment: @mr.mams, then it will be absolutely identical to another python answer

Answer (score 13):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 20 bytes

`s[-1].ord` will give us the codepoint of the last character in the string, which we can then plug into this formula:
$$(160 \bmod c) \bmod 7 $$

```ruby
->s{160%s[-1].ord%7}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf16642tDMQLU4WtcwVi@/KEXVvPZ/QWlJsUJatJKVhlIsF5xTg8zRROa4IHN0UTTpoujSRdGmC9T3HwA)

Comment: Nice find on the formula! I tried brute-forcing for expressions in Python no longer than `160%n%7` (7 bytes) and got only that with nothing shorter. Here are the 8-byte ones: [TIO](https://tio.run/##Vc/dboIwFMDxa3mKc3MQCBu2pXw04UmWZSFaJ5kpBKqZWfTVGYXVsrsfJ@Xf0@6mT62i4yi/u14OQ9OqASpoVHfRQejpuv@U@uPQ7PU0/Ul3AnYxpEQAjYHQVACJISsEsLt3bHtwlSmx@hqEt6n3p0Ze5WGuTTEl5LU@B@5QCCYx/7m69/VL3oYgvHubrm@Uhn8ZqKr12XF826qIIyEJ28YwuUgeKabGefRQyZ9JxvFFYT47pyuXzkXmXLKnVUSRlEtHRQxtf3aJ5eIMCbfzDPnTOXKK3Jj5y3aLl@3s3NxgbW6wNlVnzt0bfebe6DO3p7WpWJuKMzd@/wU "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 12):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>11</s> 8 bytes

*3 bytes saved thanks to @Bubbler!*

```apl
⊃'(|)'⍳⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOuZnWNGk31R72bH/Xs/f8/TUHdSkOdC0TVQChdKK0JoVygoi7qAA)

```apl
       ⌽  reverse the string
⊃         take the last (now first) byte
 '(|)'⍳    index inside '(|)' (if not found ('D') returns the length (3))
```

Comment: [8 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOuZnWNGk31R72bH/Xs/f8/TUHdSkOdC0TVQChdKK0JoVygoi7qAA)

Comment: @Bubbler Unfortunately, it says the link can’t be decode; mind repasting?

Comment: @AviF.S. [Here it is](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOuZnWNGk31R72bH/Xs/f8/TUHdSkOdC0TVQChdKK0JoVygoi7qAA). Weird though, because I can open it fine on my PC.

Comment: Very odd! Still doesn’t work for me but I’m on the mobile app (iPhone). Though I couldn’t find anything on Meta re: bugs with TIO and mobile... Suppose I’ll just hold my excitement ‘til I can check on my computer :)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```python
lambda e:"(|)D".find(e[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIdVKSaNG00VJLy0zL0UjNVrXMFbzf2pufklmcn5eMVBlNJeSlaaSDpDUdQFTNRCOhhJXLBdXWn6RQqpCZp4CXIsVl4JCQVFmXolGmkaqpuZ/AA)

Because we don't care about the eyes/nose, we can just look at the mouth (the last character) and find its index in a string with all the mouths, ordered from saddest to happiest :) Thanks @Surculose Sputum!

Comment: `find` works the same as `index` and saves 1 byte

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda s:160%ord(s[-1])%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRodjK0MxANb8oRaM4WtcwVlPV/H9BUWZeiUaaRmZeQWmJhqam5n8rXRcA)

Math taken from @dingledooper

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>37</s>  33 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes on both versions thanks to @ceilingcat and @dingledooper*

I overlooked the rule about the optional nose, so this is not as effective as expected.

```c
f(char*s){s=390%~-s[*++s%9<1]&3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLO62NbY0kC1Trc4Wktbu1jV0sYwVs3YuvZ/WX5mikJuYmaehqZCNZeCQkFRZl5JmgaQpaCgpJqigA0p6YCl0zSUrDSUNBEcXRReDYoUCk8TRQqF54IiBeQBOZrWXLX//yWn5SSmF//XLQcA)

#### How?

Among the characters that we have to deal with, the hyphen is the only one whose ASCII code is congruent to \$0\$ modulo \$9\$. We use this property to decide whether we need to work on the second or the third character.

Given the ASCII code \$n\$ of the relevant smiley character, we apply the following formula to get the happiness:

$$h(n)=(390\bmod (n-1))\bmod 4$$

---

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/),  <s>36</s>  32 bytes

Using [Uriel's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202898/58563) is 1 byte shorter.

```c
f(char*s){s=s[*++s%9<1]*2%19&3;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLO62LY4Wktbu1jV0sYwVstI1dBSzdi69n9ZfmaKQm5iZp6GpkI1l4JCQVFmXkmaBpCloKCkmqKADSnpgKXTNJSsNJQ0ERxdFF4NihQKTxNFCoXngiIF5AE5mtZctf//JaflJKYX/9ctBwA)

Comment: [-1 byte for both](https://tio.run/##jc7LDoIwEAXQPV8xIUHbaoPCCohx4y@4c0OqdEh4GOpjgfjpVnwkMsaFSRe9uXOTo6RWylrNFKaNMLw1C2GkXGpmJgGPw2jmXaUwozDpHN@HdZPvirGBrG7KY5E6@L3D104YEXjz6DGzpzrfQpnmFePQOgD7Jq8OGet/AK63hV9vU7nT54Fmbsxc/gmSpAupSOKkImlFqj71gSd/0t4wHMKQwHAIQwLDIQwJDIcwJLDO3lRWpNpYeb4D), by recursively searching for the end of the string.

Answer (score 5):

### Excel, 25 bytes

```
=FIND(RIGHT(A1),"(|)D")-1
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
⁽$9,4ḥ’
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields an integer in \$[0,3]\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R414VSx2ThzuWPmqY@f//fysXAA)**

#### How?

```
⁽$9,4ḥ’ - Link: list of characters, A
⁽$9     - base 250 literal = 10058
   ,4   - pair with four
     ḥ  - Jelly hash A using 10058 as a salt and [1,2,3,4] as the domain
      ’ - decrement
```

---

Previous **8** byter:

```
“|)D”iⱮS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5waTZdHDXMzH21cF/z//38rFwA)

#### How?

```
“|)D”iⱮS - Link: list of characters, A             e.g. ":-)"     OR  ":-("
      Ɱ  - map across c in A with:
     i   -   first index of c in (or 0 if not found):
“|)D”    -     list of characters = "|)D"               [0,0,2]       [0,0,0]
       S - sum                                          2             0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, 17 bytes

```bash
tr '(|)D:-' 0-3\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIQV2jRtPFSlddwUDXOEbh/38rDS4r3RouKxcgpcllVQMA)

*Note: There's a space character after the backslash.*

Input on stdin, output on stdout.

The challenge doesn't specify the format of the output.  Depending on the input, this program may print the output in either %2d or %3d format (that is, with one or two spaces before the 0, 1, 2, or 3).

If that's not acceptable, then

`tr -s '(|)D:-' 0-3\`

**(20 bytes)** always prints the digit in %2d format.  (There's a space after the backslash here too.)

Or

`tr '(|)D:-' 0-4|tr -d 4`

**(23 bytes)** prints just the digit (with no spaces).

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 19 bytes

```perl6
{TR:d/(|)D:-/0123/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OiTIKkVfo0bTxUpX38DQyFi/9n9xYqWCHlA2Lb9IISczL7X4v5UGl5VuDZeVC5DS5LKqAQA)

Comment: If raku -p is acceptable, you could reduce to tr:d/(|)D:-/0123/

Answer (score 4):

## Mornington Crescent, 1820 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZXBTsJAEIbvPsWeNB7wAbxJPZgIprHofbIdYcJ2BqeDiU@Pi0ATpG2KBS497P91@v8zu9tClImnJjzwiqVHttVqAnN0L6I2Q2U3IkZn4kZIHktDddnnEhSvjsFS8h5yCuG7AidL5QVFbQTcl@rl7QBLZqCxKS5RKcvuzDA@NIhUzO@Cy0wRrQFJIc83/W8Aunyni9@xiE7BtpETUh@wQRyjqSwkkMFe3vAhbO46TsKoQG2Bn6Obm3LjJ@a/izHZK2y9vZM3UYIKz/AL2WW0nkwTs1uo9d8qDoHntcITFDFGWZDNavUEmIX35nfyCt3NPcb2aMxZEW@Lgnjdsga9f4X/9/wh5I2bbU/rv9fSeG3F4@NeBfIW7PAs9qmWEvMpXJ3hoLSX/DOLdvis0S/TwqPy1lyau79jfGX3d7wf3P4A)

A port of @dingledooper's fantastic Ruby answer, which just so happens to work seamlessly in Mornington Crescent because of a convenient `7` in it. Props to them!

```
Take Northern Line to Leicester Square
Take Northern Line to Leicester Square
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Turnpike Lane
Take Piccadilly Line to Leicester Square
Take Northern Line to Leicester Square
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Baker Street
Take Bakerloo Line to Paddington
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Bakerloo Line to Charing Cross
Take Northern Line to Moorgate
Take Circle Line to Moorgate
Take Metropolitan Line to Chalfont & Latimer
Take Metropolitan Line to King's Cross St. Pancras
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Cannon Street
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take Circle Line to Cannon Street
Take Circle Line to Bank
Take Circle Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Hammersmith
Take District Line to Upminster
Take District Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Victoria
Take Circle Line to Aldgate
Take Circle Line to Aldgate
Take Metropolitan Line to Chalfont & Latimer
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road
Take Metropolitan Line to Baker Street
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road
Take Metropolitan Line to Pinner
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road
Take Metropolitan Line to King's Cross St. Pancras
Take Victoria Line to Seven Sisters
Take Victoria Line to King's Cross St. Pancras
Take Circle Line to King's Cross St. Pancras
Take Metropolitan Line to Pinner
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road
Take Metropolitan Line to Pinner
Take Metropolitan Line to Preston Road
Take Metropolitan Line to King's Cross St. Pancras
Take Circle Line to King's Cross St. Pancras
Take Northern Line to Mornington Crescent
```

The only major thing I feel I need to point out is how I got `160` in the program. To do this, I took the first letter of `Paddington`, which gives an ASCII value of `80` when run through Charing Cross, then multiplied it by `2` in Chalfont & Latimer to get `160`. Subsequently, the program computes `160 % (ASCII of last character) % 7` via Preston Road, the formula found by @dingledooper.

Comment: Wait, Turnpike Lane exists?

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
T`-:(|)D`__d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyRB10qjRtMlIT4@5f9/K00uK10XLqsaIKUBxEAukKcL5GoAAA)

```
T`
```

Enter transliteration mode

```
(|)D`d
```

Replace the mouth character with the corresponding digit (0 to 3)

```
-:`__
```

Remove each of `-` and `:` from the string.

Implicitly output the result, which will be a single digit.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
'|)D'jmfs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X71G00U9Kzet@P9/K10XAA)

#### Explanation

```
'|)D' % Push this string
j     % Read input as unevaluated string
m     % ismember: true for chars of the first string that are present in the second
f     % find: (1-based) indices of true entries. The result will have length 0 or 1
s     % sum. This is needed to transform an empty array into 0
      % Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), `-hr`, 18 bytes

```
?^⑵¦P0|\1|R2|\¦3™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fPu7RxK2HlgUY1MR8mN/SbFgTZFQTc2iZ8aOWRf//W@mCgOZ/3YwiAA)

The same switch statement format, but with a different character checking criteria.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
θÇx19%4%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3I7D7RWGlqomqv//W7kAAA)

#### Explanation

I used Uriel's formula.

```
θ        # Get mouth (last char)
 Ç       # ASCII value
  x      # Multiply by 2
   19%   # Modulo 19
      4% # Modulo 4
```

Comment: If you don't want to have the answer wrapped into a list, you could swap the `θÇ` to `Çθ`. (PS: `x` actually pushes `2n` without popping, but there is also `·` which pops and pushes `2n`. Doesn't matter here, but figured I'd let you know in case you're using it in future answers.) Here also another 8-bytes alternative based on [_dingledooper_'s Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202907/52210): `ƵxIÇθ%7%`. [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cPu5HYe2G1qqmqjqcB3bWuEJElA1V9X5/99K1wUA)

Comment: @Kevin Cruijssen I knew that `x` did that, just that I looked for * 2 and not 2 * in info.txt. I also made a solution based on dingledooper's formula, but it was 9 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 24 bytes

```perl
s/.*(.)/ord($1)*2%19%4/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09LQ09TP78oRUPFUFPLSNXQUtVEP/X/fysNLivdGi4rFyClyWVV8y@/oCQzP6/4v25BDgA)

Steals the math from @Uriel's Python answer

Comment: Using the method in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202896/9365) is slightly shorter (abusing `-F` to get the last char): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYzLyW1QkmjRtNFSUfFLdow9v9/Kw0uK90aLisXIKXJZVXzL7@gJDM/r/i/bkGOm76GnqaKPgA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Even shorter using [@JoKing's `TR` approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202935/9365): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79SX6NG08VKV99A11g/5f9/Kw0uK90aLisXIKXJZVXzL7@gJDM/r/i/bkGOm76GnqaKPgA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｉ⌕(|)D§Ｓ±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zL0VDSaNG00VJR8GxxDMvJbVCwzOvoLQkuASoKl1DU0fBLzU9sSRVw1ATBKz//7fS1fyvW5YDAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
       Ｓ    Input string
      §     Cyclically indexed by
         ¹  Literal 1
        ±   Negated
 ⌕          Find index in
  (|)D      Literal string of mouths
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 31 bytes

Io's strings are made of integers, so character-converting is unneccecary. Although Io doesn't allow us to index the last item of a sequence using `last()`...

```
method(x,160%x reverse at(0)%7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8z/n5FYUFCpYGWrEPM/N7UkIz9Fo0LH0MxAtUKhKLUstag4VSGxRMNAU9VcE6JUQ8lKV1NJU6GgKDOv5D8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), 120 bytes

```
8a5m2x1v1a2x2v4a2x3v9a9a5a2x4v1x1f2r3x3v1e2f0x1x2f3x1v3e3x2v5e3x4v6e4f0x1x3f0m1o0x1x4f0m1a1o0x1x5f0m2a1o0x1x6f0m3a1o0x1f
```

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
8a5m2x1v                 # Set variable 1 equal to 40 ("(")
1a2x2v                   # Set variable 2 equal to 41 (")")
4a2x3v                   # Set variable 3 equal to 45 ("-")
9a9a5a2x4v               # Set variable 4 equal to 68 ("D")
1x1f                     # Function 1
    2r                   # Read the second byte in the input string, removing it
      3x3v1e             # Jump back to the start of the function if it equals variable 3
            2f           # Otherwise, jump to function 2
1x2f                     # Function 2
    3x1v3e               # Jump to function 3 if the register equals variable 1
          3x2v5e         # Jump to function 5 if the register equals variable 2
                3x4v6e   # Jump to function 6 if the register equals variable 4
                      4f # Otherwise, jump to function 4
1x3f                     # Function 3
    0m1o                 # Output 0
1x4f                     # Function 4
    0m1a1o               # Output 1
1x5f                     # Function 5
    0m2a1o               # Output 2
1x6f                     # Function 6
    0m3a1o               # Output 3
1f                       # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
x"(|)D"e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v0JJo0bTRSn1/38lKxclAA)

#### Exalanation

```
x"(|)D"e
          : Implicit evaluated input
       e  : Last element of input
 "(|)D"   : The string "(|)D"
x         : First occurrence of the last element of input in "(|)D"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 32 bytes

```
func[s][select"(0|1)2D3"last s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhIdy5Vm9T@tNC85ujg2ujg1JzW5REnDoMZQ08jFWCknsbhEoTiW639aflFqYnKGQmpuflZmNJcCEChZaShBGbo1MJYLXEgTxgLKxUJ0FBRl5pUoRBckpigAzcuFGKZgrKCka6ekkAbhxnLF/gcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

Turns out Ranges finally started to actually exist and work! Thanks to an anonymous user for pointing this out (by proposing an edit, but anonymous users cannot comment...)

```cs
s=>160%s[^1]%7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O9WmpdsU1xSlJmXrqOQmVdip@CmYKvwv9jWztDMQLU4Os4wVtX8vzVXAFBFiYabhpKVhpKmJjK/Bo2vicZ3QeProhugi26CLroRumAz/gMA)

Answer (score 2):

## batch, <s>109 bytes</s> 99 bytes

```bat
@For %%G in ("(=0",")=2","D=3","|=1")Do @Set %%G
@Set "T=%~1"
@<Nul Call Call Set/P"=%%%T:~-1%%%"
```

[image: output (TIO unavailable)]

Comment: 106 Bytes when lines are terminated by `LF` instead of `CR` `LF`, using `Shift`+`CTRL`+`J`

Comment: the space in front of `do` is optional

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

I based the logic off of the Java solution submitted April 2 and edited April 8, by branboyer. I suppose it would be referred to as a port of their answer, but I don’t know exactly how that’s supposed to be marked.

```
a=>"(|)D".indexOf(a[2]||a[1])
```

An anonymous function, taking a string and returning an integer. Please help me shorten it further, I’m new to golfing code. Just the code, without the way of inputting (no idea how to get input in try it online) is at this [Try it online link](https://tio.run/#%23y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k5Jo0bTRUkvMy8ltcI/TSMxOlEvJzUvvSRD1zBW839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahpKVhpKmpoKCvr6CARe6lG4NSA4oZYgh5QLTZYypSxOqywhDqgamy/A/AA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! As this is an anonymous function, you can remove the `b=` from the byte count. You can just link to a third party test area, such as [Try It Online!](https://tio.run) if you don't want to include the HTML/full script, which is definitely not required in your answer. As for tips on how to shorten it, I'd recommend you check out the [Tips for golfing in Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) and look at other JS answers around the site.

Comment: You can also drop the `;`

Comment: You don't need to add any HTML for javascript answers. If you want to shorten it, you can replace `a[a.length-1]` with `a[2]||a[1]`

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNFNSkxKzdHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k5Jo0bTRUkvMy8ltcI/TSMxOlEvJzUvvSRD1zBW839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahpKVhpKmpoKCvr6CARe6lG4NSA4oZYgh5QLTZYypSxOqywhDqgamy/A/AA) is a TryItOnline link of your answer, which verifies all test cases.

Comment: Thanks for the Try it online link, @dingledooper! I will edit that in instead of my link.

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://esolangs.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Esoteric_Language), 11 bytes

```
iʁ2f{J}ⱱ4ⱱo
```

Based on [Uriel's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202898/77309).

```
iʁ2f{J}ⱱ4ⱱo
iʁ          (split the face into it's ord values)
  2f        (mouth * 2)
    {J}ⱱ    (mod 19) (base 26)
        4ⱱ  (mod 4)
          o (print)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 20 bytes

```
y/(|)D/0123/;s/:-*//
```

Pretty self explanatory. Replaces the the "mouth" characters with numbers using the `y///` transform command and then strips off the eyes and the nose if they exist.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco7CoAwEAXAfk@xgkUiLM9Pt0KqFN7BT6VolSYIEXL3mGqaidcpd3jLQxEtWByDUvlgsvXoh3HCHKHSAWWhVNMWAIKsh9vRRDCYUdSQSib1FUuafw)

This is one byte longer, but perhaps it gets bonus points for having an emoticon in the code itself? `:-\`

```
y/(|)D/0123/;s/:-\?//
```

The shorter solution (16 bytes)

```
y/(|)D:-/0123  /
```

also works, but adds extra whitespace to each line of output. It also has two emoticons `D:` and `:-/`. :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/2fwVWsr6KvoGunoM9V8b9SX6NG08VKV9/A0MhYQUH/vwdXBVBBTJ6@Ppe@bnScXay@YrG@gj5IykqDy0q3hsvKBUhpclnVAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
"(|)D"bUÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Iih8KUQiYlXM&input=IjooIg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 32 bytes

The verbosity offseted the bytecount.

```erlang
h(I)->160rem lists:last(I)rem 7.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy3KScxL100tTi7KLCj5z/U/Q8NTU9fO0MygKDVXISezuKTYKiexuAQoChIw1/ufm5iZpxEdq6mga8elAASZ@VblRZklqRoZGkpWuppKmpp6/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
☻M:ù·±♥
```

Uncompressed:

```
(|)D"azx
```

### Explanation

```
         % Implicit quote
(|)D"    % The string "(|)D"
     az  % The last item of the input
       x % Where is ^ in the above string?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-1 byte thanks to FrownyFrog ang Bubbler

```
'(|)'i.{:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1TVqNNUz9aqt/mtyKXClJmfkKyhoWKdpKqjZKahbaahbA0ndGjClCeFAKRf1/wA)

Comment: You can drop `D` as bubbler pointed out.

Comment: @FrownyFrog Yes, indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 11 bytes

```
)3?11%2/(p;
```

I'm convinced my method is the smallest possible, but this isn't the best possible one - just one of the earliest low-value ones.

```
)3?11%2/(p;
)           #Pop the last element of the string (as ascii value)
 3?         #Cube the number
   11%      #Modulo 11
      2/    #Divide by 2 (round down)
        (   #Decrement by one (gotta be 0 1 2 3, not 1 2 3 4)
         p; #Print the value we want, and shunt the rest of the stack
```

I used [the following TIO](https://tio.run/##XVFRS8MwEH7vrzhSB07HGIgIDhHZFPYwFHxUH7Lmuh5kSUhS5pz97fXaKu3MS467@@77vrut1XnIPLlY19e3NIf@pStDkaSmLwSC3HqwZQRtrUvexLkQ30KMhViKD0ifvUKPCh5eF6tVcoSTlz47NB0OYHpSWZZOUyYj8mgP0nt5mLRMsaDwB6HxQBeLyjzK0EjaHMAa5I4TwvSJ8SizAlDjDk0EMv34pGkZv/fzXqxjNoTI/y9gAoojFtXkC2m2ZLYgRAu9uu@JFuUG2ySN@uTaKiDOVqOhprV0nadoey2wR3Do2e@Od8dk7EpmkawJUDprmnVNz@4GB8m7IR2ag2B9ZKjUvBLVeDvSpauO84ry1punxn6EPcWCFxaidJr7rWmtoVETsBz5PTF1KErulkaBR4cyJtW/Oy605bb2Kjez2cWw9PiJWckb4zxE2mGo6x8) to search for answers, and 11 popped up quite early. I also tried squares and higher powers, but they weren't as clean and short.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmvZKXrovRf09je0FDVSF@jwPr/fwA)

[Every case!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/P1rJSkNJQcmqBkRogggXEKELFtQFi@qChXVdlGK5qrm4NI3tDQ1VjfQ1Cqy5uGpVuf5z/QcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org) `-p`  23 Bytes -> 19 Bytes

```
$_=(4-.ords[*-1]*2%5)%4

$_=160%.ords[*-1]%7      #(with @dingledooper's formula)
```

Comment: 17-byte port of the Perl 5 `-p` solution: `tr:d/(|)D:-/0..3/`

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 16 bytes

```powershell
2*$args[-1]%19%4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/d9ISyWxKL04WtcwVtXQUtXkfy2XjTKXAhBYaVgpGEBYNVYKhhCWppWCEYTlYqVgzKVsx8WlrqGuo14DxJpA7KJeo1rNxalSYaugZKUSrwRkVoKYumC2kkqFApCnraGmkqbgUKEJEqlEEqnU5Kr9DwA)

PowerShell port of the modulo formula going around. Takes input via splatting

Answer (score 1):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 38 bytes

```
Mod[2Last@ToCharacterCode@#,19]~Mod~4&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d83PyXayCexuMQhJN85I7EoMbkktcg5PyXVQVnH0DK2DihfZ6L2X9@hWslKQ0lHyaoGRGiCCBcQoQsW1AWL6oKFdV2UamP/AwA)

This borrows [Uriel's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202898/41938), which happens to be the same length as [dingledooper's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202907/41938), but I can't help but wonder if another formula would be shorter. I will investigate.

For comparison, here's the string indexing solution (51 bytes):

```
("(|)D"~StringPosition~Last@Characters@#)[[1, 1]]-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/V9DSaNG00WpLrgEyE8PyC/OLMnMz6vzSSwucXDOSCxKTC5JLSp2UNaMjjbUUTCMjdU1VPuv71CtZKWhpKNkVQMiNEGEC4jQBQvqgkV1wcK6Lkq1sf8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [MAWP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 27 bytes

```
|2W!!92W1MP92W1MWA!!4P4WA:.
```

[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=%7C2W!!92W1MP92W1MWA!!4P4WA%3A.&input=%3A-%7C)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, 2335

`(・・?` Did somebody say emoticons?

```js
a = 
// The function:
(w)=>{(笑)=(w);ﾟωﾟﾉ= /｀ｍ´）ﾉ ~┻━┻   //*´∇｀*/ ['_']; o=(ﾟｰﾟ)  =_=3; c=(ﾟΘﾟ) =(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟｰﾟ); (ﾟДﾟ) =(ﾟΘﾟ)= (o^_^o)/ (o^_^o);(ﾟДﾟ)={ﾟΘﾟ: '_' ,ﾟωﾟﾉ : ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ] ,ﾟｰﾟﾉ :(ﾟωﾟﾉ+ '_')[o^_^o -(ﾟΘﾟ)] ,ﾟДﾟﾉ:((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_')[ﾟｰﾟ] }; (ﾟДﾟ) [ﾟΘﾟ] =((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ) ['c'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [ (ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)-(ﾟΘﾟ) ];(ﾟДﾟ) ['o'] = ((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟoﾟ)=(ﾟДﾟ) ['c']+(ﾟДﾟ) ['o']+(ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_')[ﾟΘﾟ]+ ((ﾟωﾟﾉ==3) +'_') [ﾟｰﾟ] + ((ﾟДﾟ) +'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+ ((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) - (ﾟΘﾟ)]+(ﾟДﾟ) ['c']+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ)+(ﾟｰﾟ)]+ (ﾟДﾟ) ['o']+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ];(ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] =(o^_^o) [ﾟoﾟ] [ﾟoﾟ];(ﾟεﾟ)=((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+ (ﾟДﾟ) .ﾟДﾟﾉ+((ﾟДﾟ)+'_') [(ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟｰﾟ)]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [o^_^o -ﾟΘﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ==3) +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]+ (ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_') [ﾟΘﾟ]; (ﾟｰﾟ)+=(ﾟΘﾟ); (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]='\\'; (ﾟДﾟ).ﾟΘﾟﾉ=(ﾟДﾟ+ ﾟｰﾟ)[o^_^o -(ﾟΘﾟ)];(oﾟｰﾟo)=(ﾟωﾟﾉ +'_')[c^_^o];(ﾟДﾟ) [ﾟoﾟ]='\"';(ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] ( (ﾟДﾟ) ['_'] (ﾟεﾟ+(ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ ((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (c^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(oﾟｰﾟo)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ) .ﾟΘﾟﾉ+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (o^_^o)+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ ((o^_^o) - (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (o^_^o)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟｰﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(oﾟｰﾟo)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (o^_^o))+ (ﾟДﾟ) .ﾟΘﾟﾉ+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (o^_^o)+ (o^_^o)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((o^_^o) +(o^_^o))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+(ﾟΘﾟ)+ (o^_^o)+ ((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟεﾟ]+((ﾟｰﾟ) + (ﾟΘﾟ))+ (ﾟΘﾟ)+ (ﾟДﾟ)[ﾟoﾟ]) (ﾟΘﾟ)) ('_');}
// Execute function:
a(':D');
```

I took it from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205865/91403), encoded it with [aaencode](https://utf-8.jp/public/aaencode.html), and wrapped it an the arrow function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 14 bytes

```perl
y/(|)D:-/0-3/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r1JhqxJvzZWckZ9boKFSoWn9v1Jfo0bTxUpX30DXWD/lv7VKhZ6tkoJSaV5OanExUIltXa6@rr6mNRdEQtdOQQnIjrdVUqlQiVf6b6XBZaVbw2XlAqQ0uaxq/uUXlGTm5xX/1y0AAA)

Basically a port of my [sed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211823/58834), but the `y///` command in perl has the additional utilities of deleting extra characters and specifying ranges of characters, so this manages to be shorter and still contain `:-/` and `D:` as essential parts of the code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 20 bytes

```
[ last "(|)D"index ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQnFpYmpqXnFqsUFCUWlJSWVCUmVeiUFiuYM3FVVhezaUABFYaEEq3BkK7QLmaELqGq/Z/tEJOYnGJgpJGjaaLUmZeSmqFQuz/3MQCheKSxORsvf8A)

### Explanation:

If `":)"` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `last` Take the last element of the input.

  **Stack:** `41` (code point for `)`)
- `"(|)D"` Push a string to the stack.

  **Stack:** `41 "(|)D"`
- `index` Find the index of `41` in `"(|)D"`.

  **Stack:** `2`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `K`, 7 bytes

```
td19%4%
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=td19%254%25&inputs=%3A-D&header=&footer=)
-1 thanks to exedraj.

Comment: [7 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=td19%254%25&inputs=%3A-D&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 94 bytes

```
,[[>++<-]>>,]>++++[<++++>-]<[+++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>[-]<<<[>>>>>+<<]>>]>-[>+<-----]>---.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCYBQDEMHqnEACTm5RelBBUEED4Lzf9MckkdSur/b9ZzfcY8xZSqCKGkqU0SyXSimkymoveShWybLqWz20Aq68wn8jGiZgXmMBesP)

Uses [Uriel's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202898/41938). Here's how it works:

```
,[[>++<-]>>,]
```

A nifty input loop that handles the optional nose and doubling the characters. It gets a character, doubles it into the next cell, then moves two cells over and tries to get another character. At the end, the tape looks something like

```
0 2*c1 0 2*c2 0 2*c3 0 ...
                     ^
```

This requires an implementation with EOF=0 or no change (which accounts for most of them including TIO).

```
>++++[<++++>-]<
```

Put 16 after the last doubled input. Now on to the main loop:

```
[+++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>[-]<<<[>>>>>+<<]>>]
```

This loop will

- add 3 to the dividend (current cell). I do this because it's 2 bytes shorter to get 16 rather than 19, and these can be reused to construct 4 for the second dividend.
- compute the modulus of the previous%current cell.
- clear out a temporary variable
- check if the value of the cell 3 indices back is non-zero (which is only true on the first iteration since the loop ends 2 indices to the right of where it started). If it is, increment the cell where the next dividend will be (this sets up the second modulo 4).

For clarity, here's what the tape looks like during the first iteration, before the tempvar is cleaned:

```
0 2*c1 0 2*c2 0 0 tmp 2*c3%19 0 ...
                  ^
```

And the same for the second:

```
0 2*c1 0 2*c2 0 0 0 0 tmp 2*c3%19%4 0 ...
                      ^
```

So checking the cell 3 indices back is an easy way to see which iteration we're on without using a counter.

```
>-[>+<-----]>---.
```

And finally, a bit of wrapping abuse to add 48 to the result so it can be outputted.

There's probably room for improvement, particularly in the input loop or the memory layout, but this is the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `tB`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṇ;Œ7%
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU4NyUzQiVDNSU5MjclMjUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lM0EtKSZmbGFncz10Qg==)

Uses dingledooper's formula.

##### Explanation

```python
ṇ;Œ7%  # Implicit input
       # Convert to codepoints
ṇ;     # Push compressed integer 160
  Œ    # Take 160 mod each codepoint
   7%  # Mod each by 7
       # Implicit output of last item
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org),  <s>27</s>  24 bytes

-3 Refactor to remove `it.`

```
{"(|)D".indexOf(last())}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xDsIwDEX3nsLKZA/tASIVFhYkJAZOYLUJRAQTNQEhtT17cBn463t6//4sMUh9c4QbpxTE5WzhUqYg1w4J2h0cpUBfZ4MLHUwXZHSfs8fIuSDRWv1L4MFBVJ4b0G0tz4ODHibH40mbyvYWjPnxpO2C/zfcXKJmrbalLw)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 34 bytes

```
SELECT CHARINDEX(RIGHT(@,1),'|)D')-1
```

Requires the variable `@` to be declared and assigned the input.

This code takes the right most character, and searches an indexed list of the possible mouthes. `CHARINDEX` returns a 1-based index. *But*, failing to find anything returns 0. So we leave the frown out of the search string (making the sad face even sadder).

[Try it online! (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/81684)

Answer (score 0):

### [Hy](https://github.com/hylang/hy), 33 bytes

```
(fn[s](%(%(*(ord(last s))2)19)4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYqxCgIxEER7v2JZEHYEC8XGra/3A2KKAxUDZwyXveME/z2uFjIwM/De/dWkXm2mhWRI1UgefWlyy6FGWXs28hwvMvSOKrDH7ogD0AKrMLFu39/G73YcAaykjCkbccplMqWgQq6RwqeL53yazAH/xQXtAw)

It's a basic port of [Uriel's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202898/94080). I might be able to shorten it by getting rid of a `%` but I need to play around with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

## [MAWP 0.1](https://esolang.com/wiki/MAWP), 27 bytes

```
|2W!!99M1MP99M1MWA!!4P4WA:.
```

Uses the modulo formula from @Uriel 's answer

Answer (score 0):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 10 bytes

```
-1='(|)D'?
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X9fQVl2jRtNF3f7/fytdFwA)

### Explanation:

```
-1=        # Gets the ASCII value of the final character. 
   '(|)D'? # Finds the index of that ASCII value, in the string '(|)D'.
```

And then, the index value is implicitly printed.