# Derivative of a product

Tags: code-golf, string, calculus

In calculus, the derivative of a mathematical function defines the rate at which it changes. The derivative of a function `f(x)` can be marked as `f'(x)`, and these can sometimes be abbreviated to `f` and `f'`.

The derivative of the product of two functions `fg` is `f'g + g'f`. The derivative of three `fgh` is `f'gh + fg'h + fgh'`. In general, the derivative of a product of any number of functions is the sum of the product of all but one, multiplied by the derivative of the remaining one, for each individual function.

Your challenge is to take a string of distinct alphabetical characters and transform it into its derivative. No spacing or simplification is required, and terms separated by `+` may be in any order. The string will contain at least two characters.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code wins!

### Testcases

```
abc -> a'bc+ab'c+abc'
de -> d'e+de'
longabcdef -> l'ongabcdef+lo'ngabcdef+lon'gabcdef+long'abcdef+longa'bcdef+longab'cdef+longabc'def+longabcd'ef+longabcde'f+longabcdef'
short -> s'hort+sh'ort+sho'rt+shor't+short'
```

Comment: Can we assume all letters are distinct?

Comment: @att Sure, tht's fine.

Comment: Is output with a leading `+` acceptable?

Comment: @DLosc I'm gonna say no to that one.

Comment: do the functions in each term need to remain in the original order?  In other words, is a```abc'+bca'+cab'``` an acceptable output for ```abc```?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen That's a tricky one... I'm gonna say no simply because it's a major part of the challenge, and pretty much all answers would have to change to remain competitive under that.

Comment: Desmos would be perfect for this challenge if we didn't have to output the formula and could output values

Comment: If a leading `+` were acceptable, it could be done in a [one-pass regex substitution](https://regex101.com/r/qLf8X7/1).

Answer (score 25):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
aRL#aJ'+<>#aJ''
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbrE4N8lBO91LVt7ECUOkQUKrkiWikxKTlFKRbKBwA)

#### Explanation

```
aRL#aJ'+<>#aJ''
a                Command-line arg       "abc"
   #a            Length of arg          3
 RL              Repeat-list            ["abc"; "abc"; "abc"]
     J'+         Join on "+"            "abc+abc+abc"
        <>#a     Groups of size len(a)  ["abc"; "+ab"; "c+a"; "bc"]
            J''  Join on "'"            "abc'+ab'c+a'bc"
```

Answer (score 12):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 54 bytes

```
lambda s:((l:=len(s))*(l*"'"+-~l*(s+"+")))[-~l*~l::-l]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXISc5NSEhWKrTQ0cqxsc1LzNIo1NbU0crSU1JW0detytDSKtZW0lTQ1NaNBvLocKyvdnFiobqeCosy8Eo00DaVEoAouBC8JjZucgiGQmpaeARSEmLRgAYQGAA)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 56 bytes

```
lambda s:((l:=-~len(s))*(l*(s+"+")+-~l*"'"))[l:-3*l:-~l]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXISc5NSEhWKrTQ0cqxsdetyUvM0ijU1tTRytDSKtZW0lTS1gYJaSupKmprROVa6xlpAoi4nFqrfqaAoM69EI01DKRGogAvBS0LjJqdgCKSmpWcABSEmLVgAoQE)

### Old [Python](https://www.python.org), 58 bytes

```
lambda s:((l:=-~len(s))*(l*(s+"+")+l*"'"+"+"))[l:-3*l:-~l]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3rXISc5NSEhWKrTQ0cqxsdetyUvM0ijU1tTRytDSKtZW0lTS1c7SU1JXATM3oHCtdYy0gUZcTCzXBqaAoM69EI01DKRGogAvBS0LjJqdgCKSmpWcABSEmLVgAoQE)

### How?

```
 a b c d +
(a)b c d +
 a(b)c d +
 a b(c)d +
 a b c(d)+
 ' ' ' '(')'
 a b c d(+)
 a b c d +
(a)b c d +
 a(b)c d +
 a b(c)d +
 ' ' '(')' '
 a b c(d)+
 a b c d(+)
 a b c d +
(a)b c d +
 a(b)c d +
 ' '(')' ' '
 a b(c)d +

   etc.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>69</s> <s>64</s> 59 bytes

-10 thanks to @Noodle9 and @ceilingcat

```c
l;f(char*a){for(l=0;a[l];)printf("+%.*s'%s"+!l,++l,a,a+l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcpBDoIwEIXhvbewCbFlinE/8STIYqwUSMaWdOqKcPYCe3m7l@93jWMKQymMXruRUk1m8TFpfj6QWu7QzGkK2WsF1b2WWyUKrmwB2JIlYINr@dIUtFkue0RvpwzOvyxavUJzbP@HfPoT4BiG3Et2JGeJjDHlf7aWDQ)

Answer (score 8):

## [Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>87</s> 84 bytes

```
>,>---[>+<+++++++]>++[>,]<[<]<[<]>[[.>]>.>[.[-<<+>>]>[.>]<[<]<++++.----[->+<]<[<]]>]
```

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to Nitrodon.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCcAwDAMHcuwJjBYRfiSBQin0Uej8bpwK9NAJaTz9vI93XploUFVCXH4FRIgWTt8GaQgYaFR3wQpFdl8D0zrQ9bBZIDL7mB8)

**Explanation**:

```
memory progress for abc:
null a null 'bc
null ab null 'c
null abc' null

string is split to two parts by null character

>,>                load first character
---[>+<+++++++]>++ load ' to memory; taken form esolangs wiki
[>,]               load rest of input
<[<]<[<]>          go to beginning of memory
[ 
 [.>]              print first part
 >.>               print '
 [                 check if there is text after '
  .                print first char of second part 
  [-<<+>>]         move char to the first part
  >[.>]            print rest of second part
  <[<]<            go to position of '
  ++++.----        use ' to print plus
  [->+<]           move '
  <[<]             go before beginning
 ]
 >                 move back to beginning
                   if there wasn't text after ' move after end instead
]
```

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes by moving `'` after printing the rest of the second part.

Comment: @Nitrodon Thank you, it saved even 3 bytes!

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 47 bytes

```py
lambda s:"+".join(s.replace(c,c+"'")for c in s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY39XMSc5NSEhWKrZS0lfSy8jPzNIr1ilILchKTUzWSdZK1ldSVNNPyixSSFTLzFIo1odqcCooy80o00jSUEpU0NbkQvCQ0bnIKhkBqWnoGUBBi0oIFEBoA)

How it works:

```
a  b  c  d --> a' b  c  d 
a  b  c  d --> a  b' c  d 
a  b  c  d --> a  b  c' d 
a  b  c  d --> a  b  c  d'

then join with '+'
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 53 bytes

```factor
[ dup length [1,b] [ cut "'"glue ] with map "+"join ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcyxCsIwGATgvU9xZHFQBFd9AHFxEafS4W/620TTJE3@UEF89prN7biPuwdpCWm93y7X8xGZ58Jec97zWxLlf4GJxOwT@bHmFyfPDjZgXnBqmnn5gHqNgeGCH4WzaMqMbEISfNcWQ4lwXMmgPez6Di10EaiNGl1hdFhspYki1FY9g/Xo6iom66WiDlMM9Y9Jm/UH)

If the order of each product doesn't matter:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 43 bytes

```factor
[ all-rotations [ 39 suffix ] map "+"join ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcwxDoJAEEbhnlP8oTXaWKEHMDY2xopQjOsgq8vOsjMEEuPZkc72y8tryZnk5XY9X04HKA8jR8e649ky6R/w5hw5wAuGCceiGKYP6O7wYASJT2M1R8rQTrLhu9SgELZZjMxLVNTYV9Cxbf2MBj0llJvyJT6iWduUfbTVnfRJ1guT65Yf)

### Explanation

```
                  ! "short"
all-rotations     ! { "short" "horts" "ortsh" "rtsho" "tshor" }
[ 39 suffix ] map ! { "short'" "horts'" "ortsh'" "rtsho'" "tshor'" }
"+"join           ! "short'+horts'+ortsh'+rtsho'+tshor'"
```

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <strike>46</strike> 44 bytes

```javascript
l=>[...l].map(s=>l.replace(s,s+"'")).join`+`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBta4QwDMff36cochCld@VuGwzm6j6IE9QaH26dFduNgfjZXas7dX2R/Jom/6S5Zd@ZFn3TmXOrCpxKPkkexYwxmbDPrPM1jyTrsZOZQF@fNPXACwJ2U02b0nQSqtWGGLSGk9jLcuGdiFegs1K1lQ0UWLqbrlVvvCQ8LCX406EwWCxlkAua5eCMgFkBkBY4o4RVh0oFO25hxxXs2AmubHU3FrBj22VjhB2Xc2sNbmiqa1icgsX1sDgD24dEjeID@/k/718Pz0/zJhxdH11WqXriSzSksSmX0LrXdQlMYluZOiSUNgEZDsQel@qW6nYbN1bgHkQbvBf@e9D2ofRNsETcVEoik6ry0@NgRnKOyHHQozV/s8aac45v15dLMqa2bJx@AQ)

-2 bytes thanks to [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)

Comment: This answer only works with 'distinct alphabetical characters'.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) page for ways you can golf your program! In particular, you're generally allowed to take input as a char array instead of a string, and `.join('+')` can become `.join\`+\``

Comment: @emanresuA The problem with "[taking] input as a char array instead of a string" is that `.replace` would be messed up. Is there another thing you're suggesting that will allow there to be less bytes with regards to the char array?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Oh, never mind :P

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 14 bytes

```
J‘œṖ€j€”'j”+”'
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJK4oCYxZPhuZbigqxq4oKs4oCdJ2rigJ0r4oCdJyIsIiIsIiIsWyJhYmMiXV0=)

```
J‘œṖ€j€”'j”+”'  Full Program
J               [1, 2, ..., len]
 ‘              [2, 3, ..., len + 1]
  œṖ€           For each of these, partition (*)
     j€”'       Join each partition on ' (**)
         j”+    Join on +
            ”'  An unparseable nilad forces the current string to be printed

(And then the ' is printed at the end)

(*)  partition takes a list on the left but since we give it a single number,
     it auto-wraps it so we just get all needed splits
(**) the last partition only has one sublist so join doesn't work properly here
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>45</s> 36 bytes

```
aRiffle[a/.#->#<>"'"&/@a,"+"]<>""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P/H9pIVBmWlpOanRifp6yrp2yjZ2SupKavoOiTpK2kqxQJ7S/4CizLySaKBkmoNzRmJRYnJJalGxg3KsWl1wcmJeXTWXUmJSspIOl1JKKojMyc9LBwqkpKaBeMUZ@UUlSly1/wE)

Input `[{characters...}]`. Assumes all characters in input are unique. Returns a string.

---

#### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
ToString@Expand[Dt[1##]/._@a_:>a']&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYq9CsIwGAD3PEZS6qIWV8ESUHchbiGUr/lpCk0i6TcoYl89tsvBHRcAvQ2Ao4biqkt5JoF5jAO/v18QjbyhPDGmmmPHoTu3sFN1eawDSnZoXcW5@IQ@TQ2/esig0eaZM1UvQkNcvoRCr@meUGM3TikOazDWbTb7lJGSX/kD)

Input `[symbols...]`. Assumes symbols are unique and not defined. Returns a spaced string.

`Dt`  treats strings as constants.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <del>15</del> 13 bytes

```
L$|+`.
$>`'$'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/30elRjtBj0vFLkFdRf3//8SkZAA)

-2 thanks to Neil.

Match every character. For each one, take the text before the separator after the matched string, followed by an apostrophe, followed by the text after the matched string. Print as a list with separator `+`.

Comment: ``L$|+w`.`` / ``$>`'$'`` is 14 bytes. (But I didn't know you didn't need the `'` before the `+`; that's only documented to work with `¶`.)

Comment: Make that 13 bytes, because I forgot to remove the `w`.

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 21 bytes

Most straightforward K  solution.

```
{"+"/?[x;;"'"]'1+!#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pW0lbSt4+usLZWUleKVTfUVlSuqOXiSlNKTFICkmnpGSCqOCO/qATEyMnPS09MSk5JTVPiAgDpMhDX)

#### Explanation

```
{"+"/?[x;;"'"]'1+!#x}
     ?[x;;"'"]          / insert "'" in string at 
              '         / each position
               1+!#x    / 1..len of string
 "+"/                   / join the resulting strings with "+"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <sup><s>83</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>72</s></sup> 69 bytes

```javascript
s=>g=(r="",i=0)=>s[i]?g(r+("+"+s).slice(!i,++i+1)+"'"+s.slice(i),i):r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZHhasMgEMe/7ymcFE4xLe02GDSzfZCu0NRcEjeJRd0YlDx7pkmXZn64@/n37jzPj@K78MrpS1i2tsS@kr2Xu1oyJynNtFxzufMHfdzXzAlGBRWer7zRCtmjzoTQYsMFhSjfVM0zzbeuV7b1gQSMRpIDLc6KZoSWmKyxbR2FEqu08411gR7zhzEFfy6oApZjGpyVKM6QjIKhAqAocUADUx1hLMy4hRnXMONUcOJY984KZhxvuTPCjKvhag@paeEbGJ2F0TkYXYD7g1SD6hPd8J73r6fXl2ESiTbPKaqyjjCDgegYss6je5uGsDLY1qHJSZw0J9cHElcKTUNNs40/k08iRvEv8d@BjwcVC5zxUUt9WYMrY2t2WlxDR5Y7srj6LppbtwcvpcT9Zrs@dqeY1vW/)

*Saved <s>7</s> 8 bytes thanks to [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a)!!!*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Samathingamajig](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98937/samathingamajig)!!!*

Comment: `r.join\`+\`` and `s[i-1]` I think

Comment: @emanresuA Very nice, this is my first JavaScript golf so thanks very much! :D

Comment: You might be able to save some more bytes by using a string for `r` although conditionally adding the `+` might cost more bytes than it's worth.

Comment: Maybe if you conditionally add the `+` and just return `r` at the end?

Comment: @emanresuA Found it! Thanks for the encouragement. :)))

Comment: You can save [one more byte](https://tio.run/##VZBha8IwEIa/@ytCEC4hKtYNBmr0h3SCNb222UIjSTYG0t/eJe3Urh/unr65e3O5j@K78Mrpa1i2tsS@kr2Xh1oyJyldaJlxefC5XmanY82cYFRQ4fnKG62Q6f1moUXGBYWo3kU@aFvXK9v6QALGIElOi4uiC0JLTNHYto5CiVX68411gZ52s7EFf66oApZjG1yUKC6QgoLBAVCUOKCBh48wFibcwoRrmHAyfHD0fbKCCcdbnoww4Wq42kMaWvgGxmRhTA7GFOD5INWg@kQ3vOf9a/P2OmwiUfaSqirrCDMYiI4l611M@8cSVgbbOjQ7IoTm5DYj8Uulaalpt7mOBncRo3hv/Hfg40HFAmd81NJc1uDK2Jqd57fQkeWBzG@@i@Fv2txLKfGYbden7hzbuv4X) with a different calling pattern.

Comment: @emanresuA Oh wow! That's very interesting - thanks again! :D

Comment: You can save [three more bytes](https://tio.run/##VZHhasMgEMe/7ymcFE4xLe02GDSzfZCu0NRcEjeJRd0YlDx7pkmXZn64@/n37jzPj@K78MrpS1i2tsS@kr2Xu1oyJynNtFxzufMHfdzXzAlGBRWer7zRCtmjzoTQYsMFhSjfVM0zzbeuV7b1gQSMRpIDLc6KZoSWmKyxbR2FEqu08411gR7zhzEFfy6oApZjGpyVKM6QjIKhAqAocUADUx1hLMy4hRnXMONUcOJY984KZhxvuTPCjKvhag@paeEbGJ2F0TkYXYD7g1SD6hPd8J73r6fXl2ESiTbPKaqyjjCDgegYss6je5uGsDLY1qHJSZw0J9cHElcKTUNNs40/k08iRvEv8d@BjwcVC5zxUUt9WYMrY2t2WlxDR5Y7srj6LppbtwcvpcT9Zrs@dqeY1vW/) by changing where `i` starts and exploiting the prefix increment operator

Comment: @Samathingamajig Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⪫⪪⪫Ｅθθ+Ｌθ'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPI7ggJxPK9E0s0CjUUSjU1FFQ0lYCkj6peeklGRqFmiARdSVNTev//xOTkv/rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @DLosc's Pip answer.

```
    θ       Input string
   Ｅ        For each character
     θ      Input string
  ⪫         Join on
      +     Literal string `+`
 ⪪          Split into substrings of length
        θ   Input string
       Ｌ    Length
⪫           Join on
         '  Literal string `'`
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
J''CL¹J'+SRL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/30td3dnn0E4vde3gIJ/////n5OelJyYlp6SmAQA)

Same approach as [DLosc's Pip answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247001/95126).

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 28 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
{1↓⥊'''∾˘⟨∘,≠⟩⥊«⥊'+'∾˘⊢⌜˜}
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkHsx4oaT4qWKJycn4oi+y5jin6jiiJgs4omg8J2VqeKfqeKlisKr4qWKJysn4oi+y5jiiqLijJzLnPCdlal9CgpGICJsb25nYWJjZGVmIg==)

returns the required string with a trailing space. removing that is +3 bytes

-3 from ovs, who also made this [tacit](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkDHihpPin5zipYonJyfiiL7LmCgx4oC/MCviiaAp4qWK4p+cwqvin5zipYonKyfiiL7LmOKKouKMnMucCgojIG9yOiAx4oaT4p+c4qWKJycn4oi+y5go4p+o4oiY4p+p4oi+4omgKeKliuKfnMKr4p+c4qWKJysn4oi+y5jiiqLijJzLnAoKRiAibG9uZ2FiY2RlZiI=).

Comment: `'''` feels so cursed to me lol

Comment: [save 1 byte](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=I0bihpB7MeKGk+KliicnJ+KIvsuY4p+o4oiYLOKJoPCdlanin6nipYrCq+KliicrJ+KIvsuY8J2VqeKlisuc4oi+y5ziiaDwnZWpfQogRuKGkHsx4oaT4qWKJycn4oi+y5jin6jiiJgs4omg8J2VqeKfqeKlisKrKOKIvicrJ+KIvsKo4omg4qWK4ouIKfCdlal9CgpGICJsb25nYWJjZGVmIg==) by changing ```⥊'+'∾˘⥊˜∾˜≠``` to ```(∾'+'∾¨≠⥊⋈)```.  Still seems a bit awkward, though...

Comment: `⥊˜∾˜≠` can be `⊢⌜˜`. Then [tacit](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkDHihpPin5zipYonJyfiiL7LmCgx4oC/MCviiaAp4qWK4p+cwqvin5zipYonKyfiiL7LmOKKouKMnMucCgojIG9yOiAx4oaT4p+c4qWKJycn4oi+y5go4p+o4oiY4p+p4oi+4omgKeKliuKfnMKr4p+c4qWKJysn4oi+y5jiiqLijJzLnAoKRiAibG9uZ2FiY2RlZiI=) is the same length

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 21 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
1↓⟜∾'+'∾¨1↓↑∾⟜'''⊸∾¨↓
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgMeKGk+KfnOKIvicrJ+KIvsKoMeKGk+KGkeKIvuKfnCcnJ+KKuOKIvsKo4oaTCgpGICJhYmMi)

`↑` gives prefixes, `↓` suffixes. `∾⟜'''⊸∾¨` joins matching prefixes and suffixes with a single quote.

`1↓` removes the first value (empty prefix ∾ `'` ∾ full suffix).

`'+'∾¨` prepends a + to each string.

`1↓⟜∾` joins the string and removes the leading +.

Comment: [20 bytes](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4oi+4p+cJysn4oq44oi+wrQx4oaT4oaR4oi+4p+cJycn4oq44oi+wqjihpMKCkYgImFiYyI=) using Fold to join the string

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ż\'vṀ\+j
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLFvFxcJ3bhuYBcXCtqIiwiIiwic2hvcnQiXQ==)

No clue why I didn't vectorise insertion back in May 2022.

### Explained

```
żƛ?n\'Ṁ;\+j
żƛ           # For each item P in the range 1...len(input):
  ?n         #   at position P in the input,
    \'Ṁ      #   insert a '
       ;     # end map
        \+j  # join the result of that on "+" and output
```

Comment: I have a completely different 11

Comment: interesting. I'm still golfing so maybe I'll break 12

Comment: @emanresuA is that the 11 you had?

Comment: Yep :) - Maybe there's something better

Comment: A flag to make implicit stack pushing in lambdas use the input instead of lambda arguments would be useful

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 83 bytes

```bash
v=$1\';until [ $v = \'$1 ];do a+=+$v;v=$(sed "s/\(.\)'/'\1/"<<<$v);done;echo ${a#+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFha4MwEP3eX3GkgVNC13Xsw4a6Dbr9CtMPMcYqK7FoKkLxt7tL22UbC5j37nzvuNwVqq/n6mS1a1oLVRTDeR4yvpGYnKxrDpADHyADiXwDu6RsQYlM8CEhUdSbEli/ltGdjHGNcrNmaZryISadNYnRdQv8rJZimqdFafRBdQZWCpzpXRYxVWgGrDR0HVq7p7A0FQV93XaOxb8dZjwa7Ux5daFQBWqh8FYARYl/q6AIHKvA0QSOZeCoA8cicFSB4z5wtIHjv5ZReEDnATsP2HrA/@/RtdGfpqPnyPHjQY7PW/oeqdAtfJfj05YsVdtBFEGT3SfQpIyfl9@TyN92E0tAiCb2414AHZeRwg835w39veSMzwXTT76n/VXAuG/s4iUbhT2DLCM0V9Wxa6y7yGD1Aryndd5az/nrbpKWLfyq5y8)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 151 bytes

```c
char*f(char*c,int i){char*r=malloc(i*i+i);char*o=r,k=0;for(;k<i*i;){if(k++%(i+1)==1)*o++='\'';*o++=*c++;if(!*c)c-=i,*o++='+';}*o--=0;*o='\'';return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBBboMwEEXXcAo6FcLGQwWJujLORRoWxEAYQXBlyApxdmqcqlI3nu83X@M/1tld633XfW3TjvmikaYlIr76m1WPehyNZpSSIC49NMrioHLZGcvkULqW5Ct1bBAiZiQKrlTBUyOESq5JIr1KtRDSed5SzXWmCF99kcgtNVnmprmx3m7b5WmnyMptf6dJj8@mjcp5aUa6ffSX8B8jc6Aj8KOmifE1DHzCaGnnZf6q1Ar1TQOeEZoW8IQwmunuUNN2gEWOMPfGLoCfCM5WIADmmwyDYzX/Dy4YlYU7hDrxMAi@rcMdg3iOsksUz9cJ8PUYVdixP/krRFFxLsNt/wE)

Comment: [122 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY/BboMwDIbP8BSZJyRCzARtd1hD2gfZOFADrQUjU6Cnqnt1Fug0aRf71/dbtn9Kz0Tz3MaELOlSuYT0be3OUNX3lmJGVrnExBqHncl0a12su4IT1k8JHSk17E2lzG67z2SnVPTNxuTHlW3f9tnDTUgpnaSp9Uy7Zrq6QTh9n595oP5aN6IYp7rn08vlEP5jbBfEwyQ@Kx5ieQuD9UExNeM0vpfmBtWJALcIdQO4QejtcPaoblrAPEMYL9ZNgK8IfixHAMzuOgyWIMta9qG4yH1RZiPDIPhyHrcxRKNIDyIaPwbAxzEusY3/5K9QeSmlDu/zDw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 40 bytes

```
a->join([replace(a,i=>"$i'") for i=a],+)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYsxDsIwEAR7v-JkIcUWTkVD43wEpTjiC1xknSPH4TM0aSKewFv4DUFhq9Xs7HMd5si4vB6YdaX9Ope-Pn8M1s2QWMwl0xixI4OOfaMPXGkLfcrAHlt3tH__9EMFWCAThshCk7EKtoyZpUQxxYEG34B2UCqrSMJ-Xd547VQgFZPcthqoV9M95bLPXw)

only works with all letters distinct

##### Why...how...what...

- `[... for i=a]` iterates over the string `a` and store the results in a list. `i` will be a `Char`
- `replace(a, i=>"$i'")` replaces all characters equal to `i` in `a` with `i` followed by `'`
- `join(..., +)` joins the list with `+`. `+` is a function, so `string(+) == "+"` is used.

Comment: Why...how...what... Can you remove the space between the `)` and the `for`?

Comment: @emanresuA sadly no. It might have been possible in older versions of Julia

Comment: I will add an explanation

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>81</s> 75 bytes

*Edit: -6 bytes thanks to Giuseppe*

```r
function(x,`[`=substring)paste0(x[1,s<-1:nchar(x)],"'",x[s+1],collapse="+")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TczBCsMgDADQf8llSjOo1zG/RApNbdoJEouxxb/vdtz5wav3yjVd1NLF/t5OiS0VMR3nMHs9F201yW4P0saj6cGhvp/uJfFD1XQ7ITwAe9DBTRhLznQoexjA/r0GcpGdlrjy9oMv)

Takes advantage of the vectorization of `substring` over a vector of start (& optional end) positions, and the vectorization & argument-recycling of `paste` over vectors of strings to paste-together.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##TczBCsMgDADQf8llSjOo1zG/RApNbdoJEouxxb/vdtz5wav3yjVd1NLF/t5OiS0VMR3nMHs9F201yW4P0saj6cGhvp/uJfFD1XQ7ITwAe9DBTRhLznQoexjA/r0GcpGdlrjy9oMv)

Comment: @Giuseppe - Ow.  How on earth did I manage not to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 58 bytes

```
s->j=strjoin;j([j(strsplit(s,c),Str(c"'"))|c<-Vec(s)],"+")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwFESv8vkbE0z2orZLLyC4KUVqmtSEkob8uBC8iZuAiGfyNqbYzQxvmJnnJ3TRnoeQXwaq9y0ZufluSdauohTdZP3OscaxAhRGmxgJxcUxRaZwhZw_1F6etGLEW4Fr5MvDoQthvDMCWUOI1pcd4AwIpnS5gAa7i0IB2OtZx8kPJei1mYmuU0zYLm85__0H)

A port of [@att's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246988/9288).

Takes input as a string. Requires that all characters are unique.

---

### [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 64 bytes

```
v->i=1;j=strjoin;j([j([j(v[1..i]),j(v[i++..#v])],"'")|c<-v],"+")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxBCsIwFESvEr4L82kS6E6oLV7ArZsSJMa2ppQ2JDEgeBM3BRHP5G1sqzDMvLeZx9sqZ46NHZ81yV_XUPPNZxd5YfI0a3MfXDuYPmtpuSSWqRBGIpvRJIkQqyhRMlgD3vWWxwkTwP_PXlnb3agnvCDWmT5MCLMAqemh0tQjIiMlqJMGRuBczd0NfRMqH7Tyi_vL4ALI_-k4_vYL)

Take input as a list of characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 14 bytes

```
.
$`$&'$'+
.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX49LJUFFTV1FXZtLT4Xr///EpGSulFSunPy8dCAzJTWNqzgjv6gEAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.
$`$&'$'+
```

Replace each variable with its derivative multiplied by the other terms plus a trailing `+` to sum the products together.

```
.$
```

Delete the final trailing `+`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṛ€j”+sLj”'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hztmPmtZkPWqYq13sA6LU/z/cselwO1Aw8v//xKRkhZRUhZz8vHQgMyU1TaE4I7@oBAA)

Port of [DLosc's Pip solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247001/85334)

```
 €            For each element of the input,
ṛ             the input.
  j”+         Join the copies on +,
     sL       split into slices the length of the original input,
       j”'    and join those on '.
```

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
p”'$ṛ¦ⱮJj”+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/gUcNcdZWHO2cfWvZo4zqvLCBX@//DHZsOtz9qWhP5/39iUrJCSqpCTn5eOpCZkpqmUJyRX1QCAA)

The implementation of `¦` is a bit questionable, so we can just abuse Cartesian product to make up for it.

```
p”'            Pair each element of the input with ',
   $ṛ¦         and substitute elements of that into the input at
      ⱮJ       each index, individually.
        j”+    Join the results on +.
```

Just for fun, without preserving the order within each term, `ṭ-Ƥ”'ż@j”+` is 10.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ε''«Nǝ}'+ý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FZ19UOr/Y7PrVXXPrz3//@c/Lz0xKTklNQ0AA)

```
ε       map each character (of the implicit input string)
 ''     the ' character
 «      append to the current character
 N      iteration index
 ǝ      replace the input string's Nth character with the character with ' appended
}
'+      + character
ý       join by it
```

Comment: Nice answer, +1 from me, but you forgot to remove the explicit `Iy` inside your TIO link. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 52 bytes

```
~(:-&(:& &:sub|(~:%&(~:+&?')|:& &:*)|:|&A)).D|~:*&?+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWN03qNKx01TSs1BTUrIpLk2o06qxU1YCEtpq9umYNWFgLSNeoOWpq6rnU1FlpqdlrQ_SuKygtKVZwi1ZKTEpOUYqFCC5YAKEB)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¬£i''YÄÃq+
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rKNpJydZxMNxKw&input=ImFiYyI)

```
¬£i''YÄÃq+     :Implicit input of string
¬              :Split
 £             :Map each element at 0-based index Y
  i''          :  Insert a "'" in U at index
     YÄ        :  Y+1
       Ã       :End map
        q+     :Join with "+"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 33 bytes

This 33-byte version works on my local recent-ish version of Raku:

```
{join '+',.comb.map:{S/$^a/$a'/}}
```

But not on TIO, where a few more bytes are needed:

```
{join '+',.comb.map:{$^a;S/$a/$a'/}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLDkAwFAXQrdxIowPCzMBvE@bkofWJelIm0nTtJTmDcyl7FMG8iDWa4HbeTshEptnEZswMXaUTPVVdLugnc@/DTS8iMaBp4TTE4CNotqhpnDArHHwuf2elca9snzZ8)

- `.comb` breaks the input string up into characters.
- `.map: { S/$^a/$a'/ }` returns a copy of the input string for each character, in which that character has had an apostrophe appended to it.
- `join '+'` joins those strings together with a plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 36 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.chars.map{s.sub _1,'\&\''}*?+}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3VXTtiquL9ZIzEouK9XITC4Ds4tIkhXhDHfUYtRh19Vote-1aiNp1BaUlxQpu0UqJSckpSrEQwQULIDQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 123 bytes

```rust
|s|{s.chars().map(|_|s).enumerate().map(|(i,w)|{let mut t=w.repeat(1);t.insert(i+1,'\'');t}).collect::<Vec<_>>().join("+")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZG9bsIwFIXVMXkK46HXViCIreJv6SNU6lSJGueGpA0OtS9iSHiSLgztQ9GnqUMKpAMefD7bR0dH159fduvocJSpYWuVGyFZFQYFEkvGLDXi3pGVbDBnT2Rzs2Iz9r2ldPBwrGpXVy7WmbJOyHitNqJe1E7GaLZrtIrwfCvy_k7WVZO53hKj2S62uEFFYiQnFOfGoSWRR6M-vAD4q72MdVkUqGk8nj6jni7mcx_2Vvp6POJy31b4uXsNJmEwHLLHDPU7I3TEtHLowkC5JnSBHz2RCK6Wmss-4wqWOlJLaDYNXE7CkPn135zgyZsARgneMhWlWfmMBFNv5gVcjlFRQocNdHgFHW66XNhXurKGDvsaV0bocHqrm8tKS00tBw1FLoNWSmjFQit0Sgg2_mOpMD3Bqz3vs_O8_NPfoA-HVn8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes

```
*"+".,,@::`<$_"'"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWG7WUtJX0dHQcrKwSbFTildSVIOJQ6QXbE5OSuVJSuXLy89KBzJTUNK7ijPyiEog0AA)

```
*"+".,,@::`<$_"'"
*                 Join
 "+"               with plus signs
    .              for each n in
     ,              range
      ,              length
       @              input
        :           join
         :           join
          `<$         first n characters of
             _         input
              "'"      apostrophe
                      the remaining characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 20 bytes

```
JiTjiS{''IC}Z[[-'+IC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc69CoMwFAXg3acQlzMEn0Do4mTp1kKh0sEk158SDCY6ic@eehE0S86XQ8i9cnGG/LRQWLM0v6VZUeTfcB9ev@G5AlW5feo6h6jKsL0foZGKXzWQSjQSfCgkmrjUIKEJibFjt9eaWm4NzqswFpFHRO4Qmb8/vU@5rBB5H3iZELlF4nvrZl7AgyV8jyMsjnA4YsYf)

```
J      # Dup
iT     # Tails
j      # Swap
iS     # Heads
{
 ''IC  # Intercalate "'"
}Z[    # Zip together then map
[-     # Drop head
'+IC   # Intercalate "+"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 99 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
N	X =X + 1
	I TAB(X) . L REM . R	:F(O)
	O =O "+" L "'" R	:(N)
O	O TAB(1) REM . OUTPUT
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hMuPM0LBNkJBW8GQCygY4uikEaGpoKfgoxDk6gukgzit3DT8Nbk4/RVs/RWUtJWAMkrqSiBxDT9NLn@gOEiPoSZUvX9oCMhUVz@X//9z8vPSE5OSU1LTAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 150 bytes

```go
import."strings"
type S=string
func f(s S)S{b:=[]S{}
for i:=range s{k:=""
for j,d:=range s{k+=S(d)
if j==i{k+="'"}}
b=append(b,k)}
return Join(b,"+")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9BasMwEEX3OoWYTSSSdF0MukBXBS1DKbIluYrjkZDkRTG6RjfdmEIP0aP0NpWTFEJWw39_mP_n86v3y09Q3aB6Q0flkLgx-JgfwI4Zvqds94-_H_8s5eiwT0DyezBUiosmdsKOWpao5HJuG3F4kXMh1kfqGhEV1tNpHhoBcIbHnb7BWyGZ5sRZehTCrRo2UApphQrBoGbtbuCFRJOniPTJO6wEtsDLtd3rOX7tzjidyXOtlE_ILAPVdsD5LdHmDpw89nVNG3tnpLf68cquMctymX8)

#### Using `strings.Builder`, 153 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)string{b:=Builder{}
w:=b.WriteRune
for i:=range s{w('+')
for j,d:=range s{w(d)
if j==i{w('\'')}}}
return b.String()[1:]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9LCsIwFEXnWUXIpAlqwZkUMnEFogMHKpI2SY22qeSDg5KFiJMiuAiX4m7sR0EcXTjvwL3vds-r5nlm2YnlApZMaaDKc2VcjGTp0MM7OZm9rl9mnVE6twhIrzMosYUDIUPUaULnXhVcmDqAS0LTeG2UE0uvBZCVgSqhhum2ydYXHI0i0tPjmP9yToCS8Eip6qRtFJEQAjDCeaNhGq_6Kkw202QXPgP3_Z5uPiawBovWcIXGEiOWZoiQX8LFHygqnbcaF_LvYA_t0x371DTNkG8)

Surprised how the string builder solution is only 3 bytes logner.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
j\+XRQ\'Sl
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=j%5C%2BXRQ%5C%27Sl&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abc%22%0A%22de%22%0A%22longabcdef%22%0A%22short%22&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
j\+XRQ\'Sl  | Full code
j\+XRQ\'SlQ | with implicit variables
------------+--------------------------------------
    R   SlQ | For each 1-index d of the input,
   X Q\'    |  Insert "'" into the input at index d
j\+         | Join with "+"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 78 bytes

```python
d=lambda s:'+'.join([s[:i+1]+'\''+s[i+1:] for i in range(len(s)) if i<len(s)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsMgEIXhfU8xZKODUAjdSXsS68JETabYMaibnt4KhUJ27/t5x6ftmW@9@0dy78U7qFoocX1lYmmq0aRmq8RTCFXN2NpCzAUIiKE43oJMgWVFBIpA9x8s9qMQN@nl5JZ1Qrz87cOJKfM2Lj7EU657Lm2U/gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>49</s> 47 bytes

```arturo
$[s][join.with:"+"map..1size s=>[insert s&"'"]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?PBUHM3)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 104 bytes

Swift is not a good language for string manipulation.

```swift
{var a=""
for i in $0.indices{var c=$0
c.insert("'",at:c.index(after:i))
a+=c+"+"}
a.popLast()
return a}
```

Type is `(String) -> String` or `(Substring) -> String`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCsMgEEDRvaeQIVAHQ8iiq4A36CUGo@1sjIzTplBydtt0@d9vO2e99l6Fi7rPi8RSADB5E8uWix3micvKMbX/jGGYTfxRS6IOLjCSLmev6e0oa5KFEQ35ED14OAxNdas3aurQSNKnFEuHg3x/MCD2/gU)

### Swift, 120 bytes

Not as short, but I think the way that `a` is initialized is funny.

```swift
{var a=[$0][..<0]
for i in $0.indices{var c=$0
c.insert("'",at:c.index(after:i))
a+=[c]}
return a.joined(separator:"+")}
```

If `Array` is a pair `(pointer, length)`*, indexing operations are like this:

- `arr[i]` = `*(pointer + i)`
- `arr[i...]` = `(pointer + i, length - i)`
- `arr[..<i]` = `(pointer, i)`
- `arr[...i]` = `(pointer, i + 1)`
- `arr[i..<j]` = `(pointer + i, j - i)`
- `arr[i...j]` = `(pointer + i, j - i + 1)`
- `arr[...]` = `(pointer, length)`**

So, `arr[..<0]` creates an empty collection no matter what the array is. Here, I'm applying it to the array literal `[$0]`, which you would never do in practice but is technically legal.

*It's actually a triplet `(pointer, length, capacity)`, but this gets the point across.

**Yes, this exists for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 93 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().mapToObj(e->s.replace((char)e+"",(char)e+"'")).reduce("",(a,b)->a==""?b:a+"+"+b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/LjsIwDDxvv8LKZRNB8wGsCj8A4gC31R6cNGVT0ofiFGmF@PbiLhHjizVjezwt3rBs6@s8TiZ4CzYgERzQ93AvCmD4PrnYoHWwZwoyTin6/gKNzA2pr3/t8VqihImv7SFANVO5JW1/MZJUusPxPBxNK93CRjcGPi3lIiu3EmL9bj@FUjxQT6wvPK6NKrdYVULszAZXgsuo@eWb38@@t8HX0HGI/N73D2C8kLoXH6c/Sq7Tw5T0yFIKvQy6kQKNZb93iMf8BA)

---

Another close solution not using Streams (**95 bytes**) :

```java
s->{String r="";for(String c:s.split("")){r+=(s+"+").replaceAll(c+"\\+{0,1}",c+"'");}return r;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 16 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 13.17 bytes

```
LDIA*'+sjsAp''sj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYbfFw8HbXUtYuzih0L1NWLsyDCUNkFixOTkiFMAA)

Port of DLosc's Pip answer.

##### Explanation

```
LDIA*'+sjsAp''sj  # Implicit input
LD                # Length of input and duplicate
  IA*             # Wrap input in a list and repeat length times
     '+sj         # Join this list by "+"
         sAp      # Split into chunks of length of input
            ''sj  # Join this list by "'"
                  # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 72 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFBbsIwELzzipWFZFsJUblWDVLv5dQXOM4GXEwSxVaFinhDD5V64iF9Dx/oE9I1LiYX7@x6d8aedVpZNXbVG2oPa2VawIPHtnbw3PdwHGtsoBH28dUPpt3I0hamrY1GV@xVL0y5skWvvN4Kkzs2P1ph5ImzfCllsd/FIcEyJkeAd2XBo/NQwotxXjBVaZYDqzGctms3VCC9kLltN3gmZ3EKDz09D@vbJJUBmOKVzlTFw6FJM1ZrjlmNKbU88Wa24xPc8gne8AkOxAkT/x1rPsGkdMfIJ7hJ8o6Hj2Ruy2PoeAwDj8FzRo23f@ot6h0OyaDL@fv35zP4cTl/kRvU1nQDCOFzQAlPi@jnh@mTRRKOV@VA54ioEV6mwpV/rYYdXfxrCdOAoMYyEC4BrUN4iBM9Lc/bVtBePSxWMHcwTwzX3Zxmp9n4Bw)

```scala
def f(l:String)=l.indices.map(i=>l.patch(i,s"${l(i)}'",1)).mkString("+")
```

Ungolfed version

```scala
object Main extends App {
  def f(l: String): String = {
    l.indices.map(i => l.patch(i, s"${l(i)}'", 1)).mkString("+")
  }

  val test = List("abc", "de", "longabcdef", "short")
  val expected = List(
    "a'bc+ab'c+abc'",
    "d'e+de'",
    "l'ongabcdef+lo'ngabcdef+lon'gabcdef+long'abcdef+longa'bcdef+longab'cdef+longabc'def+longabcd'ef+longabcde'f+longabcdef'",
    "s'hort+sh'ort+sho'rt+shor't+short'"
  )
  val checker = List("✖️", "✓")

  for ((t, e) <- test zip expected) {
    val s = f(t)
    val checkMark = checker(if (s == e) 1 else 0)
    println(s"$t -> $s $checkMark")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 21 bytes

```
/$"_+_"≡⍜↻(⊂@')+1⇡⊃⧻¤
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAgLyQiXytfIuKJoeKNnOKGuyjiioJAJykrMeKHoeKKg-Knu8KkCgpmICJhYmMiCmYgImRlIgpmICJsb25nYWJjZGVmIgpmICJzaG9ydCIK)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (Node.js), 114 bytes

```
function a(b){l=b.length;s="";for(i=1;i<=l;i++){if(i>1)s+='+';s+=b.substring(0,i)+"'"+b.substring(i,l);}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxLDsIgFIXhuatomBRCbXSMuBegQK9BruHhpOnasXFkDKOTfMl/HuqtsknwKueIi23N1WgKYBwU1WwLUs/BRl9WkSUhwmGiIK8CbjII4Jxt4CjcryxzOfJRHKPnXHUuCaKnlwkYJyPhvwhTYGJPttQUhyz2ZjBmDHYO6KmixHnC2OkPlTaL7fhSn7rDAaP/Jq7X9I7yiqkc3j4)

I forgot to add "+"

+10 characters to remove a trailing '+'

Comment: `slice` instead of `substring` is shorter.