# Is this position a pure mirror mate?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid, chess

### Task

A *pure mirror checkmate* is a checkmate position, where the mated king is surrounded by **8** empty squares which are attacked or guarded by the winning side ***exactly* once**. You will be given a valid chess position where Black is in mate. Your task is to find if that mate is a *pure mirror checkmate*.

##### Examples <sup><sub>(click for larger images)</sub></sup>

1. This is a pure mirror mate. Squares f5, g5, are protected by the king only, h5, h6, h7 by the rook only and f6, f7, g7 by the two knights only.

   [image: First example]

---

2. This position does not match the criteria. It is a mirror mate, but *it's not pure*, as d7 is guarded by the bishop **and** attacked by the rook.

   [image: second example]

---

3. This position is not a pure mirror mate as well, since the king is not surrounded by 8 empty squares.

   [image: third example]

---

4. This is a pure mate, but not a mirror mate (not all 8 squares surrounding the king are empty), therefore it doesn't meet the criteria:

   [image: fourth example]

### Input

As mentioned above, your input will be a **valid** chess position, where black will be in mate. You may take the input as an [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) or as a grid/matrix/2D array. From the examples above:

1. first position:

   ```
   4N2N/4q3/6k1/8/5K2/8/8/7R

   . . . . N . . N
   . . . . q . . .
   . . . . . . k .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . K . .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . R
   ```
2. second position

   ```
   8/R7/4k3/2P3P1/3K4/7B/8/8

   . . . . . . . .
   R . . . . . . .
   . . . . k . . .
   . . P . . . P .
   . . . K . . . .
   . . . . . . . B
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . .
   ```
3. third position

   ```
   7b/8/8/5N2/8/7k/5N2/7K

   . . . . . . . b
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . N . .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . . k
   . . . . . N . .
   . . . . . . . K
   ```
4. fourth position:

   ```
   2NN4/4k3/1b2NNb1/8/6N1/8/6K1/q6n

   . . N N . . . .
   . . . . k . . .
   . b . . N N b .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . N .
   . . . . . . . .
   . . . . . . K .
   q . . . . . . n
   ```

### Rules

- The chess position will *always* be valid and black will *always* be in mate.
- There will be no double checks (the king won't be attacked twice).
- You can receive input through any of the standard IO methods.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Can't search `guard chess` on google, all is some variant with a piece named guard

Comment: @l4m2 In this context, _S guarded by X_ means that the square `S` is not currently attacked by the white piece `X` but it would be if the black king moves there. (Like the white bishop on d7 in the 2nd test case.)

Comment: Maybe add cases where tile is guarded but not attacked?

Comment: and case where king is double attacked. Likely one would just check the 3x3 range get attacked exactly once

Comment: @l4m2 the original definition says double check is allowed if the mate could be parried without it. For simplicity, in the positions given, there will be no double checks.

Comment: @double-beep maybe update the question accordingly

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + [chess](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), <s>175</s> <s>166</s> 161 bytes

```python
def f(e):b=chess.Board(e);s=b.attacks(k:=b.king(0));b.remove_piece_at(k);return(any(len(b.attackers(1,q))>1or b.piece_at(q)for q in s)or len(s)<8)^1
import chess
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBBbsIwEEX3nCJi5ZHaTJ2EOCLQBdtIFuIARXFwSmRwEttU4ixs6KK9U29TJy1IbEZ_Ru_PfM3luzu7fauv16-Tq5-zn8-drIOaSJiLZbWX1oartjQ7P8jtUoSlc2WlLFFz36hGv5MXgFyERh7bD7ntGlnJbemIgtxIdzKalPpMDlKTm1caS-hTD_BKWxOI8G7pofaDPmh0YMGrwWRhkcEbnTTHrjUuGAP9B710ptGO1GSa8Ihj0seYKooZzorI1wzZZgowuVMZbhgmKsZoHa8pxkWCbDWADxQTo3fGhx1MjYIVD0jEeTIuosJLMZxM-VgLin2qPfwX8fbTXw)

-9 bytes thanks to rule clarification by @l4m2
-4 bytes because I realised I could just use `chess.Board` instead of `chess.BaseBoard`

Takes the fen as input and outputs `1` for a pure mirror mate and `0` otherwise. Using the chess library certainly made this easier. Explanation:

```python
def f(e):
    b=chess.Board(e)                # Generates the board with the input fen
    k=b.king(0)                     # Finds the square of the black king
    s=b.attacks(k)                  # Get a generator of all squares surrounding the king by finding the squares he attacks
    b.remove_piece_at(k)            # Remove the king from the square to allow us to find guarded squares
    return(
        any(                        # If any of the following return True
            [len(b.attackers(1,q))>1# There is more than one attacker
                or b.piece_at(q)    # Or there is a piece present
                for q in s]         # In the squares surrounding the king
            )or                     # or
        len(s)<8                    # There are less than 8 squares surrounding the king
        )^1                         # Flip boolean and return
```

Comment: Why add king to generator?

Comment: @l4m2 to check that there is only one piece putting the king in check. For some reason I thought that was a criteria, but reading the comments it doesn't need to check for that

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>381 334</s>  330 bytes

```javascript
B=>(Q=q=>B.some((b,i)=>b.some((R,j)=>q?+q?'*kk'[(K-i)**2+(L-j)**2]==R&&!(Q[++k,[K,L]]^=1):!eval(q,x=I-i,y=J-j)&R=='.'&&Q(1,K=i,L=j):(I=i,J=j,h=(m,n,r=4,p=i+m,q=j+n,x=B[K=p])=>x&&(x[L=q]in{k,'.':0})?Q(1)|h(m,n,r,p+m,q+n):r&&h(n,-m,r-1),z={N:`x*x-5`,P:`-x`,K:`x*x>2`}[R])?Q('y*y+'+z):R in{R,Q}&&h(1,0)||R in{B,Q}&&h(1,1))))(k=0)|k<8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZNdT8IwFIbv/RXKRdeuZ4QRTcz0QLI7KFlgt8vMQFG2wsbAkPH127HzAwNBBZ1Lmpxz@vY57bs26s660/tJOH424uShv3lMEtzYWKMdTLFml6fJqE9pD0KGtd575kKksrTO07qmS6l5VBgh0/Uqpy0jygMf0SXkgnY8ziV4Alq@f4cmsy76s@6QppBhwwhhjk2lJy6iVtYI6VATBIbQwohZtKGiJkYwQDqCGCZ4CWMM@QhSjHisCLYncOyrnWSE0MxrYeqH8VKCYlmVNasrHFsN3hbDOF/IY2ZNCBnQGIwRTAyTwQKXjhVkemZcBdC2AiMLQLwWatVg7bl@ztHm@pxrfMEs91y1cKGzzikmVNhq9VqytyWTqY9KVFPy9npzc3afxNNk2C8Pkyeq3KXemVcql2BnODuxDwck6U5@UPIx5M@SHyjiuEbFSdxc4jN2nF0H4O7p/eXXkvaetH2YIk4/qF2co7@yq/fff9Qp9F7IQhqJo@xy9h7i6Vent7c9Z1v7qxdOIRTxKUm/ocQfdm1eAA)

-2 bytes from Kevin Cruijssen

-4 bytes from emanresu A

```javascript
foo = a=>g1(k=0)|k<8;
g1 = q=>a.some((b,i)=>b.some((c,j)=>(
    I=i,J=j,
    c=='N'?g2((x,y)=>x*x+y*y-5): // Knight
    c=='P'?g2((x,y)=>y*y-x):
    c=='K'?g2((x,y)=>x*x+y*y>2):
    c=='R'?h(1,0):
    c=='B'?h(1,1):
    c=='Q'?h(1,1)|h(1,0):
    0
)));
g2 = q=>a.some((b,i)=>b.some((c,j)=>
    !q(I-i,J-j)&  // Correct destination
    c=='.'&&      // Empty 
    g3(1,K=i,L=j) // then go
));
g3 = q=>a.some((b,i)=>b.some((c,j)=>
    [,1,1][(K-i)**2+(L-j)**2]&c=='k'? // Near king
    !(g[M=[K,L]]=!g[++k,M]) // count as an attack
    :0                      // and memory the pos
));
h = (m,n,r=4,p=i+m,q=j+n,x=a[K=p])=>
    x&&(x[L=q]=='.'|x[q]=='k')? // Not blocked
    g3(1)|h(m,n,r,p+m,q+n):      // Next step
    r&&h(n,-m,r-1) // rotate 90 degree
```

Comment: `?!(g[++k,[K,L]]^=1):0` can be `&&!(g[++k,[K,L]]^=1)` for -1

Comment: Actually, same applies to the `c=='Q'?h(1,1)|h(1,0):0` -> `c=='Q'&&h(1,1)|h(1,0)` for another -1 byte.

Comment: [-5](https://tio.run/##tZNdT8IwFIbv/RXKRdeuZ4QRTcz0QLI7KFlgt8vMQFG2wsbAkPH127HzAwNBBZ1Lmpxz@vY57bs26s660/tJOH424uShv3lMEtzYWKMdTLFml6fJqE9pD0KGtd575kKksrTO07qmS6l5VBgh0/Uqpy0jygMf0SXkgnY8ziV4Alq@f4cmsy76s@6QppBhwwhhjk2lJy6iVtYI6VATBIbQwohZtKGiJkYwQDqCGCZ4CWMM@QhSjHisCLYncOyrnWSE0MxrYeqH8VKCYlmVNasrHFsN3hbDOF/IY2ZNCBnQGIwRTAyTwQKXjhVkemZcBdC2AiMLQLwWatVg7bl@ztHm@pxrfMEs91y1cKGzzikmVNhq9VqytyWTqY9KVFPy9npzc3afxNNk2C8Pkyeq3KXemVcql2BnODuxDwck6U5@UPIx5M@SHyjiuEbFSdxc4jN2nF0H4O7p/eXXkvaetH2YIk4/qF2co7@yq/fff9Qp9F7IQhqJo@xy9h7i6Vent7c9Z1v7qxdOIRTxKUm/ocQfdm1eAA) by extracting the y*y