Interpret PlusOrMinus
PlusOrMinus is an esoteric programming language invented by Esolang user PythonshellDebugwindow.
Language specification
There is a wrapping byte accumulator (incrementing 255 results in 0 and decrementing 0 results in 255) in the language. The initial valus of the accumulator is 0.
There are two instructions in the language:

+, which increments the accumulator by one.
-, which prints the accumulator as ASCII (e.g.: A if accumulator is 65), then decrements the accumulator by one.

Characters that are neither + nor - are ignored.
Examples
Here are some examples to test your programs:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++-+-++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-

Prints Hello, World!.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-

Prints Nope..
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------

Prints ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA.
blah

Prints nothing.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?-

Prints !.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++

Prints A.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--

Prints "!.
Goal
This is code-golf, so your goal is to use the fewest bytes to interpret the language. The program to interpret can be from a console input, file input or string.

Thanks, your test case is added!

Related

Yes, but this is a different language.

Extremely similar to this challenge.

That resets the accumulator, this just decrements it.

@WheatWizard decrementing by one rather than resetting means you cant just split on the print character and count lengths

@pacman256 I did read both challenges, that's why I linked it.

@pacman256 well, technically speaking you can still split on the print character and count lengths. It just takes a little extra processing

You can’t print as ASCII if the number is above 127, and it is dubious for numbers below 32. How should those cases be handled?

Is input guaranteed to only contain - and + or should other characters do nothing?

@Kai "Other characters are ignored" means that you do nothing when the instruction is neither + nor -.

@Tbw other characters do nothing.

@LuisMendo You can do anything in these cases (e.g.: ignore or print as extended ASCII or put in output string).

Suggested test case blah should produce no output.

Also +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?- should output !.

I think you should clarify in the question that we have to support characters other than + and - in the input string (if that's really what you want). At present, this appears clearly as part of the specification of the original language, but not as clearly as a requirement for the challenge.

@Arnauld It is already in the challenge. "Other characters are ignored"

Oh I thought that increment means to add by 1 by default.

Suggested test case (currently failing in accepted answer) ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-- should output "!.

@JonathanAllan Thanks, I've added the test case and unaccepted the Vyxal answer. I accepted the 15 bytes 05AB1E answer instead.

@KevinCruijssen Thanks for reminding me, I've checked that the Jelly answer runs successfully for the test case so I made it accepted instead.

@None1 Also, don't feel obligated to give a checkmark at all - have a look at this post on meta (currently 65 up and 18 down).

Jelly, 14 bytes
ṣ”-Ṗċ€”+’Ä‘%⁹Ọ

A monadic Link that accepts a list of characters, or a full program that accepts a string argument.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
ṣ”-Ṗċ€”+’Ä‘%⁹Ọ - Link: list of characters, Code      e.g. "---+++++--"
ṣ”-            - split {Code} at '-' characters           ["", "", "", "+++++", "", ""]
   Ṗ           - remove the (possibly empty) rightmost    ["", "", "", "+++++", ""]
    ċ€”+       - count the '+' characters in each         [0,    0,   0, 5,  0]
        ’      - decrement all values                     [-1,  -1,  -1, 4, -1]
         Ä     - cumulative sums                          [-1,  -2,  -3, 1 , 0]
          ‘    - increment all values                     [ 0,  -1,  -2, 2,  1]
           %⁹  - mod 256 all values                       [ 0, 255, 254, 2,  1]
             Ọ - convert all to characters                "\x00ÿþ\x02\x01"
               - (if running as a full program, implicitly prints to stdout)


AWK -vRS=(.), 37 bytes
RT~/+/{x++}RT~/-/{printf"%c",x--%256}

Attempt This Online!
Uses a regex as a record seperator to split the input into seperate characters and matches them one-by-one.

Works with the provided weak test cases, but try “+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++”. For this should print “A”, but your code prints ”AB”.

Thanks. The " " did something totally different from what I expected. Should be fixed now.

Perl 5 + -p055, 24 bytes
-2 bytes thanks to @Neil!
$-+=y/+//;$_=chr$---%256
Try it online!
Explanation
Cheesing a little on the args, using -055 to split input on - and using y/+// to count the +s (ignoring other chars, thanks @Johnathan Allan!).

Updated. Thanks @JonathanAllan!

24 bytes.

Thanks @Neil! I'm so certain I tried that first and hit problems with it but must've done something else!

JavaScript (Node.js), 57 bytes
Expects an array of characters and returns a string.
s=>Buffer(s.flatMap(c=>c=="-"?a--:(a+=c=="+",[]),a=0))+""

Try it online!

why was this answer accepted i am working on a 10 byter in a golflang

You didn't post it yet.

Fail -+, expected \x00, get \x00\x00

@l4m2 Thanks for reporting this. Fixed.

49 byte version when given +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?- outputs two null bytes rather than the expected ! (not handling the requirement that non-+- should be ignored).

Pip, 29 25
C{i+:Dai+1%:256}M#*H:a^'-

- 4 bytes thanks to DLosc
Attempt This Online!
C{i+:Dai+1%:256}M#*H:a^'-­⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
                     a^'-  # ‎⁡Split input by "-"
 {             }M#*H:      # ‎⁢Map through lengths of all but last item as a...
  i+:Da                    # ‎⁣ Increment i (initialised to 0) by length of a - 1
       i+1%:256            # ‎⁤ Return i+1 mod 256
C                          # ‎⁢⁡Convert codepoints to ASCII


Created with the help of Luminespire.

Here's 26 bytes.

25 by rearranging so the M and the H aren't next to each other.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?- outputs " rather than the expected ! (not handling the requirement that non-+- should be ignored).

05AB1E, 18 15 14 bytes
'-¡'+QO<ηO>₁%ç

-3 bytes thanks to @IvanG.
-1 byte porting @JonathanAllan's Jelly answer
I/O as a list of characters.
Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
'-¡           '# Split the (implicit) input-list of characters on "-"
   '+Q        '# Check for each inner character whether it equals "+"
      O        # Sum each inner list of 1s and 0s together
       <       # Decrease each sum by 1
        η      # Get the prefixes of this list of sums-1
         O     # Sum each prefix
          >    # Then increase each prefix-sum by 1
           ₁%  # Modulo-256
             ç # Convert each integer to a character with this codepoint
               # (after which the list of characters is output implicitly as result)


-2 bytes: S'-¡'+QOηOā<-₁%ç

@IvanG. Thanks! :)

Perl 5 -p, 35 bytes
s/.*?-/$x+=$&=~y-+--;chr$x--%256/ge

Try it online!

Nice use of string repetition, I came up with a very similar approach originally but didn't think to use that! (Went with cheesing -055F in the end!)

I was previously working with s/(\+)|-/$1?($x++,""):chr$x--%256/ge and also s/(\+*)-/$x+=length$1;chr$x--%256/ge with 36 bytes

@DomHastings, saved 2 bytes without using "repetition" operator but "not", and changing post-increment to pre-increment to prevent having  !0-> 1

oops i accidentally downvoted for some reason and it locked me into that, if you edit it ill upvote mb

@JonathanAllan here is a fix s/.*?-/$x+=$&=~y-+--;chr$x--%256/ge but now there's a shorter perl5 solution

Vyxal 3, 14 bytes
'-sᵛ'+Cv@₇%ꜝOṪ

Try it Online!
would be 14 if vyxal didnt automatically treat + as a regex symbol
Edit-- Bug was fixed

You need to use s instead of ÷, as ÷ doesn't keep empty splits

no clue why. it just be like that

so s doesnt keep them either

oh. huh. that's uh not a good

let me uh go fix that rq

The fix should be live on vyxal.github.io in a few minutes

This does not ignore characters that are not +- as it should. (I assume the vyxal 2 solution has the same issue)

oop let me fix that

Inputting a single string of - characters does not seem to work - it only prints one character, and it doesn't appear to even necessarily be one of the ones that should be printed. EDIT: just does not appear to deal with consecutive - properly e.g. ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-- should output "! but it only outputs ".

This doesn't work correctly for ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--, "! is expected, but " is printed.

Uiua 0.11.0, 26 bytes SBCS
▽:+@\0◿256\+-⬚0↻¯1,∩=@+,@-

Try on Uiua Pad!
Takes a string of + and - and returns the output string. If the input is guaranteed to only contain +-, we can save 2 bytes by replacing ∩=@+,@- with ¬.=@- (and probably more, with a completely different strategy).
Explanation
@-    # push literal character - to stack
@+,   # dup input to top and push +
∩=    # get two arrays with 1s where + and - are
,     # dup the - array to top
⬚0↻¯1 # shift 1 to the left, filling with 0 at front
-     # subtract from the + array
\+    # plus scan: cumulative sums
◿256  # mod 256
+@\0  # add literal character null, converts to ASCII
▽:    # flip the - array to top and apply mask


Funge-98, 47 bytes
>~#<:'+w$:'U3*-3jc+1_$0
^#:w-' <j7-1_$'U3*4j6:,

Try it online!
The program never halts, so if you run it using TIO, you have to manually cancel execution in order to view the output.

Stax, 15 bytes
Ç¿₧Δ─Θî²1%≤{‼aù

Run and debug it

Lua, 149b
Read a character from standard in, and look it up in a table of two functions - call empty function otherwise.
a=0;while 1 do(({["+"]=function()a=(a+1)%256;end,["-"]=function()io.write(string.char(a))a=a<1 and 255 or a-1 end})[io.read(1)]or function()end)()end
Lua, 109b
Read character from stdin, convert to an increment, decrement, or zero, from a table. If we're going to decrement, convert accumulator number to char and print it out before adding.
a=0;while 1 do c=({["+"]=1,["-"]=-1})[io.read(1)]or 0;io.write(c<0 and string.char(a)or"")a=(a+c+256)%256;end

Welcome to CGCC! I don't know Lua but for your interest, there is tips for golfing in Lua. Also Lua is available at Try it online! (The stdout is not printed to screen until timeout at 60s).

@JonathanAllan Thank you! Long time lurker, wanted to see what I could pull off. The regular Lua shell on my machine prints it out straight away, maybe it just hangs waiting for the next character there since it does not handle EOF

@VBW Hi! TIO is non-interactive, so you can't see thr output before the program terminates. Though I don't know Lua very much, it seems that you program never terminates. but a regular shell doesn't have this restriction.

Yes, I don't see it as a problem that you need to wait on TIO I was just letting you know.

Charcoal, 19 bytes
⭆⌕ＡΦＳ№+-ι-℅﹪⁻ι⊗κ²⁵⁶

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
    Ｓ               Input string
   Φ                Filtered where
      +-            Literal string `+-`
     №              Contains
        ι           Current character
 ⌕Ａ                 Find all indices of
         -          Literal string `-`
⭆                   Map over indices and join
             ι      Index of current `-`
            ⁻       Minus
               κ    Count of previous `-`s
              ⊗     Doubled
           ﹪        Modulo
                ²⁵⁶ Literal integer `256`
          ℅         Convert to character
                    Implicitly print


Scala 3, 123 bytes
A port of @none1's JavaScript answer in Scala.

Golfed version. Attempt This Online!
p=>{var o="";var x=0;for(i<-p){i match{case'+'=>x+=1;if(x==256)x=0 case'-'=>o+=x.toChar;x-=1;if(x== -1)x=255;case _ =>}};o}

Ungolfed version. Attempt This Online!
object Main {
  def plusOrMinus(program: String): String = {
    var output = ""
    var x = 0
    for (i <- program) {
      i match {
        case '+' =>
          x += 1
          if (x == 256) x = 0
        case '-' =>
          output += x.toChar
          x -= 1
          if (x == -1) x = 255
        case _ => // handle other characters if necessary
      }
    }
    output
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = 
s"""++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++-+-++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-"""


    println(plusOrMinus(input))
  }
}


@JonathanAllan I have fixed it.

Google Sheets, 93 bytes
=SORT(JOIN(,IFNA(CHAR(SCAN(,SPLIT(A1,"-",,),LAMBDA(a,c,MOD(a+LEN(c),256)))-COLUMN(A:ZZ)+1))))


JavaScript, 125 111 109 Bytes
r=>{f="",u=0;for(n of r)"+"==n?256==++u&&(u=0):"-"==n&&(f+=String.fromCharCode(u),-1==--u)&&(u=255);return f}

Ungolfed version:
function plusorminus(program){
    var output='',x=0;
    for(let i of program){
        if(i=='+'){
            x++;if(x==256){x=0}
        }else if(i=='-'){
            output+=String.fromCharCode(x);x--;if(x==-1){x=255}
        }
    }
    return output
}

You can run the code in this snippet:


y=r=>{f="",u=0;for(n of r)"+"==n?256==++u&&(u=0):"-"==n&&(f+=String.fromCharCode(u),-1==--u)&&(u=255);return f}
console.log(y('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++-+-++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-'))
console.log(y('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-'))
console.log(y('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--------------------------'))
console.log(y('blah'))
console.log(y('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?-'))
console.log(y('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++-++'))
console.log(y('++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++--'))




A few tips: 1. you can use a lambda/arrow function, 2. don't use var, ever 3. read https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript, 4. have fun!

Thanks for your advice!

Python, 100 Bytes
lambda x:''.join(chr(x[:i].count('+')-x[:i].count('-')&255)if x[i]=='-'else''for i in range(len(x)))

Both the argument and the return value are strings.
Explanation: + and other characters don't produce any output, the value that a - outputs equals to the number of + minus the number of - before it modulo 256.
Try it online!

87 bytes using an enumerate and moving to Python 3.8+ (to use the walrus operator, :=)

...or 70 bytes using the same approach, tracking the sum as you go.

Python 3, 66 bytes
v=0
for c in input():v%=256;v+=c=='+';v-='-'==c!=print(end=chr(v))

A full program that reads from stdin and prints to stdout.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.

brainfuck, 65 57 bytes
>,[>--[++++++<->]+<[--[[-]>-<]>[<<.->>-][-]<]>[-<<+>>]<,]

Try it online!

Pascal, 158 B
The implementation‑defined set of char values must correspond to ASCII and the ordinal value of the implementation‑defined constant maxChar must be greater than or equal to 255.
program P(input,output);var C:char;A:0‥255;begin
A≔0;while not EOF do begin
read(C);if C='−' then write(chr(A));A≔(A+ord(C='+')−ord(C='−'))mod 256 end end.

−3 B:
If you have a processor supporting “Extended Pascal” as defined by ISO standard 10206, you may write a zero‑width string:
program P(input,output);var C:char;A:0‥255;begin
A≔0;while not EOF do begin
read(C);write(chr(A):ord(C='−'));A≔(A+ord(C='+')−ord(C='−'))mod 256 end end.

Users of the FreePascal Compiler need to insert a {$modeSwitch ISOMod+} compiler directive.
This ensures an ISO‑compliant definition of the mod operator, in particular in case of negative dividends the result is still non‑negative (Euclidean‑like definition of mod).

Kotlin, 76 bytes
{fold(0){a,c->when(c){'-'->{print(a.toChar());a-1}'+'->a+1 else->a}and 255}}

Try it online!
-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat.

@ceilingcat I think you have to account for negative values.

C (gcc), 49 47 46 bytes
c;f(char*s){for(;*s;)*s++%5?c++:putchar(c--);}

Pretty straightforward.
-1 byte thanks to Arnauld.
Try it online!

Does anybody know if it's possible to save bytes with this trick?

You can use s++%5 instead of s++-45.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++?- outputs " rather than the expected ! (not handling the requirement that non-+- should be ignored).

I tried to fix the problem but my edit was rejected for I didn't "strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.", but I did

42 bytes

YASEPL, 76 75 59 bytes
=a=i=1'=l®1`1!r¥i,1}7,plus,2!+`2}7,minus,3!›-`3%256!i+}2,l


BrainChild, 97 bytes
function(int l,@int s){int a=0;int i=0;while(i<l){if(s[i]==43)a++if(s[i++]==45)putchar(a--%256)}}

Takes input as a char array
Readable
function PlusMinus(int length, @int chars){
    int acc=0;
    int i=0;
    while(i<length){
        if(chars[i]=='+')
            acc++
        if(chars[i++]=='-')
            putchar((acc--)%256)
    }
}

Try It Online!

Japt -hP, 20 bytes
q-
ÆËo+ ÅÊÃåÄ ËuG² d

Try it
q-\nÆËo+ ÅÊÃåÄ ËuG² d     :Implicit input of string U
q-                        :Split on "-"
  \n                      :Reassign to U
    Æ                     :Modify last element
     Ë                    :  Map remaining elements in U
      o+                  :    Keep only "+"s
         Å                :    Slice off first character
          Ê               :    Length
           Ã              :  End map
            å             :  Cumulatively reduce by
             Ä            :    Addition, after prepending a 1
               Ë          :  Map
                u         :    Modulo
                 G        :      16
                  ²       :      Squared
                    d     :    Character at that codepoint
                          :Implicit output of last element joined to a string


PowerShell Core, 41 bytes
switch($args){+{$c++}-{[char]($c--%256)}}

Try it online!
Function that takes a string using splatting
Returns an array of characters

J, 37 bytes
[:(]#a.{~256|[:+/\[-_1|.!.0])/'+-'=/]

Shameless port of Tbw's amazing Uiua answer.
Attempt This Online!
[:(]#a.{~256|[:+/\[-_1|.!.0])/'+-'=/]
                                    ]   NB. input
                              '+-'      NB. string literal of ops
                                  =/    NB. equality table of each op and input
[:                                      NB. cap forces f(g(x)) instead of a hook
  (                         )/          NB. fold, the two table rows become left/right arg
                           ]            NB. list of chars equal to -
                    _1|.!.0             NB. shift right 1 and fill with 0
                  [                     NB. list of chars equal to +
                   -                    NB. subtract
             [:+/\                      NB. prefix sums (sum-reduce(+/) on all prefixes)
         256|                           NB. mod 256
     a.{~                               NB. index into the ascii alphabet
   ]                                    NB. list of chars equal to -
    #                                   NB. copy with boolean vector acts as a filter


C (gcc), 59 bytes
char i;f(char*c){i+=*c==43;*c==45&&putchar(i--);f(c+!!*c);}

Ungolfed:
char i; // the counter
/*implicit int here */ f (char* c) {
    // increment the counter if *c is '+' (43), since == returns 1 for true
    i += *c == 43;
    // if c is not '-' (45), the condition will short circuit, otherwise putchar will run
    *c == 45 && putchar(i--);
    // if *c is the end of the string (0), !!*c will be 0, 
    // and the function will enter an infinite loop that does nothing, 
    // otherwise we will call f with a ptr to the next character.
    f(c + !!*c);
}

This handles non +/- characters properly, unlike the other C answer, however it does either hang indefinitely or overflow the stack (fixing this costs a byte). This also requires the -funsigned-char flag to run properly.
Try it online!

@emanresuA your code doesn't handle non +/- characters properly, if you try adding a ? to the start of the string, it breaks completely

... actually I'm dumb and missed the wrapping requirement that the char i enables, but this 58 still works

C#, 102 100 bytes
-2 thanks to @ceilingcat's suggestion to replace '+' and '-' with their ASCII codes (43 and 45)
void I(string s){byte b=0;foreach(var c in s)System.Console.Write((char)(c==43?++b-b:c==45?b--:0));}

Try it online!
Explanation:
void InterpretPlusOrMinus(string input)
{
    byte b = 0; // initialize accumulator 'b'

    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        System.Console.Write((char)( // Print the ASCII representation of:
            (c == 43)?         // If c is '+':
                 ++b - b :      //    ++b-b (increment b and return 0)
                 (c == 45)?    // Else If c is '-':
                     b-- :      //    b--
                     0          // Else: 0
        ));
    }
}

This code works in .NET 5+

Suggest 43 for '+' and 45 for '-'
