# Duck, duck, goose!

Tags: code-golf, random

Remember the kids game, ['Duck, Duck, Goose'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose)? No? Me neither.

#### The challenge

- Print the word 'duck' on individual lines an indeterminate amount of times.
- Print the word 'goose'.
- Your program ends.

#### The rules

- Attempt to play the game in the fewest bytes.
- There must be at least one duck.
- There must be exactly one goose, at the end of the list.
- There must be exactly one bird on each line. No empty lines.
- The case of the outputted strings is irrelevant.
- White-space within a line is fine.
- Your program must finish.
- Your program must not consistently produce the same number of ducks.

Have fun!

---

Please note: This question is not a duplicate of [Shortest code to produce non-deterministic output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101638/shortest-code-to-produce-non-deterministic-output)

Reasons include:

- The association to a childrens' game
- The defined start and end requirements of the result string. There is no specified output in the other challenge.
- Answers For the other, non-duplicate challenge are in a single-digit number of bytes. The average for this one is around 30, or there about.
- By the amount of overlap between this challenge and that one, any code-golf question including the 'random' tag is a duplicate. Should we delete them all?
- The code answers for this challenge would match the other challenge (in a ridiculously bloated way), but the answers to that challenge would not match this one.

Comment: Could you define indeterminate?  Could it mean either zero or one?

Comment: Please define how randomly this should be generated. Uniform in range or with exponential decline?

Comment: @recursive Nope, but let's go with a working definition... The program does not consistently present the same number of ducks.

Comment: Is any leading or trailing white-space acceptable on the lines printed to STDOUT; what about leading newline(s) or excess trailing newlines (beyond the one that I assume would be allowed anyway)?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of times one can "duck"? 1000? 100000000?

Comment: Probably anything that's finite and produces some output

Comment: Speaking as a Minnesotan, what if mine prints ["duck, duck, gray duck"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose#Duck,_Duck,_Gray_Duck) instead? :)

Comment: @MikeHill that variant intrigued me, someone else mentioned it in an answer. It’d definitely make a fun variation...

Comment: @MikeHill Was about to say the same thing!

Comment: @MikeHill, Clearly, "gray duck" is the proper output

Comment: I remember it. Am I the only one? =(

Comment: @jpmc26 I’m sure there are others. You’d have had to play it with others, for a start.

Comment: @MikeHill In Danish language, the species _mallard_ is known as "gråand" which litterally means _grayduck_.

Comment: [Relevant etymology question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/133010/115695)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
2X“¢;ÆS»ẋ“ʋ¢»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98o4lHDnEOLrA@3BR/a/XBXN5B3qvvQokO7//8HAA)

Explanation:

```
2X“¢;ÆS»ẋ“ʋ¢»

2X             Random number (1 or 2)
  “¢;ÆS»       Compressed string equivalent to "duck\n"
        ẋ      Repeat the "duck\n" that random number of times
         “ʋ¢»  Compresses string equivalent to "goose"
               Implicitly concatenated and returned
```

---

More readable version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98oQuFRw5yU0uTsQ9seNcx9uKsbxE/Pzy9OBXL//wcA)

Will always return 1 or 2 ducks.

Comment: Congrats! I have literally no idea how this works!

Comment: @AJFaraday I went ahead and added an explanation for you

Comment: @PunPun1000 Sorry, but what's the stack? Jelly is a tacit programming language.

Comment: @user202729 Oops, I got Jelly and 05AB1E messed up in my head, could you please edit it to fix that error?  Sorry about that

Comment: There's an implicit concatenation in Jelly? Yay!

Comment: @MilkyWay90 Just for clarification, the reason that this "concatenates" the output is because the final compressed string is an "unparseable nilad", meaning that the program outputs the previous result and then restarts with the new nilad. No implicit concatenation actually happens

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Okay, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 48):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 48 bytes

```fortran
f={s="duck\n";s+([s,""]select random 1)+"goose"}
```

Always prints either one or two ducks.

`random 1` returns a (floating point) number between 0 and 1. That number is passed as an argument to `select` along with the array `[s,""]`. The random number is then rounded to the nearest integer (either 0 or 1), and the array element at that index is selected from the array.

**Call with:**

```fortran
hint call f
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Alternative 56 bytes version:**

```fortran
f={s="duck\n";format[s+"%1goose",[s,""]select random 1]}
```

Comment: It always makes me glad when someone uses this on PCG.

Comment: Well i forgot this game existed.

Answer (score 42):

### World of Warcraft 81 Bytes

Here's a macro that you can run in World of Warcraft.

```
/run for x=1,random(1,9) do SendChatMessage("Duck") end; SendChatMessage("Goose")
```

Comment: Oh my lord... Why have I never thought of this.

Comment: PVCG (Programming Videogames and Code Golf). Operation Flashpoint was a thing, but WoW? I am waiting the Minecraft and Factorio solutions of this.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I suspect the Minecraft one would do a little worse than 81 bytes (blocks?) ;)

Comment: This should work and get you down to 58 bytes: `/run for x=1,random(1,9)do print("Duck")end print("Goose")`

Answer (score 42):

## Minecraft <1.13, <s>72</s> 54 bytes

Sorry, I had to.

### Instructions:

- Create a new Minecraft world in Creative Mode
- Find the save folder for that world, and place the following code in `data/functions/minecraft/ddg.mcfunction`
- Run `/function ddg` in the game console

### How it works:

Outputs the word "duck" for every entity in the world, then outputs the word "goose". Since entities are constantly spawning and despawning, the number of "duck"s will not be consistent. I used `tellraw` instead of the much shorter `say` because `say` outputs the name of the entity, while `tellraw` outputs exactly what it is told.

```
execute @e ~ ~ ~ tellraw @a "duck"
tellraw @a "goose"
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Edit: Changed {"text":"duck"} to just "duck" (and the same with "goose")

Comment: Beautiful. We need more Minecraft in PPCG.

Comment: Worth mentioning that *you* (the player) are an entity in the world, so the number of ducks can never be 0 (even if there were no hostile or passive mobs).

Comment: @BradC there should be entire challenges based around Minecraft.

Answer (score 17):

## JavaScript, <s>45</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>39</s> 37 bytes

Has the potential to produce an overflow error.

```js
f=_=>`duck
${new Date%2?f():`goose`}`
```

---

### Test it

```js
o.innerText=(
f=_=>`duck
${new Date%2?f():`goose`}`
)()
```

```html
<pre id=o></pre>
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>38</s> 33 bytes

This is not the shortest (it's 36 bytes), but it's my favorite. The explanation is in the bottom.

```
disp(['duck '+~(1:1/rand)';'goose'])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JbO4QCNaPaU0OVtBXbtOw9DKUL8oMS9FU91aPT0/vzhVPVbz/38A)

---

Some shorter variations:

This works in principle (33 bytes), but the online interpreters times out:

```matlab
disp(['duck '+~(1:now)';'goose'])
```

Adding some bytes to make the output shorter makes it 35 or 36 bytes:

```matlab
disp(['duck '+~(7e5:now)';'goose'])   % Works on octave-online.net
disp(['duck '+~(7.3e5:now)';'goose']) % Works on tio.run
```

#### Explanation:

I'll just explain the last random one. The others are similar, but uses the number of days since **January 1st, 0000** until today.

`rand` returns a random number on the interval **(0, 1)**. Thus, `1/rand` returns a number larger than **1**. Since a range `1:f`, where `f` is a random float larger than **1** is identical to `1:floor(f)`, `1:1/rand` creates a range **1 .. x**, where **x >= 1**.

I'll try to explain this as if Octave was a stack based language.

```matlab
      'duck '                           % Push the string 'duck ' to the stack
               (1:1/rand)               % Push a vector 1... floor(1/rand)
              ~(1:1/rand)'              % Negate the vector (making it all zeros)
                                        % and transpose it.
             +                          % Add 'duck ' with the vertical vector of zeros
                                        % to implicitly duplicate the string r times
     [                    ;'goose']     % Push the string 'goose' and concatenate
                                        % vertically with the rest
disp(                              )    % Display it all.
```

Comment: `disp(['duck '+~pwd';'goose'])`? Not sure if this is "indeterminate" enough

Answer (score 14):

## Z Shell (+ wget & Netpbm), <del>168</del> <del>160</del> <del>150</del> <del>148</del> <del>145</del> <del>135</del> 120 bytes

```
d(){wget -O- bit.ly/$1|jpegtopnm|pamscale -w 64 -h 64};d DckDkGo|pnmtile 64 $[(RANDOM&7+1)*64]|pnmcat -tb - <(d g005eGG)
```

Not the shortest solution, but I felt like giving a twist of sorts to this challenge (inspired by [@AlexG's solution to this other problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159718/79247)).

This script generates a PPM image containing between 1-8 pictures of ducks and a picture of a goose at the bottom on standard output. It downloads the two source pictures from Wikipedia, so internet access is necessary for it to work.

Sample output converted to JPEG through *pnmtojpeg*:

[image]

Comment: This has totally made my day!

Comment: I've just realized that you're the same person who proposed that other challenge I linked to. xD Well, I'm glad you liked this! =D

Comment: Yep, there's some themes in my code golf challenges :) I should definitely give bonus points for pictoral answers.

Comment: Isn't this a standard loophole, to get external resources?

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>36</strike> 34 bytes

```
print"duck\n"*((id(id)%5)+1),"goose"
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKaU0OTsmT0lLQyMzBYg0VU01tQ01dZTS8/OLU5X@/wcA)

Suggestion by [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) gets us to 34 bytes:

```
print"duck\n"*-~(id(id)%5),"goose"
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can golf two bytes by changing `((id(id)%5)+1)` to `-~(id(id)%5)` to get rid of the parenthesis. [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) and [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) might be interesting to read through. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Can `id(id)` not be `id(0)` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Johnathan, looking at `id(0)` on a couple different computers suggests it's a constant.

Comment: There's no rule that a program needs to run quickly or efficiently, as long as it would finish at some point on a sufficiently powerful machine and produce the correct output.  With that in mind, removing `%5` and the associated parentheses would save 6 bytes.

Comment: @user2699 I tried that, and, based on rough theoretical calculations, in about 90% of cases, you will get an OutOfMemory exception before a single character is printed.  The actual number in practice is probably much higher.  I am not comfortable with a solution that takes that risk.  I also wanted to be able to demonstrate the functionality on TIO.

Comment: Slightly more intuitive and no more bytes would be to call `id([])`. This should initialize a distinct list each time the program runs, which in theory should consistently result in different memory addresses.

Answer (score 12):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 20 bytes

First a practical 26 bytes:

Ducks 1 to 9 times before being goosed.

```perl
say"Duck
"x(1+$^T%9),Goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJpTQ5m0upQsNQWyUuRNVSU8c9P7849f//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwN9AwA)

But if you have lots of memory and time this 20 byte version (as suggested by [Chris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58834/chris)) works too:

```perl
say"Duck
"x$^T,Goose
```

This also assumes the [Year 2038 Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) will be solved for [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), otherwise it will be invalid for 1 second 20 years hence.

Comment: If you change `1+$^T%9` to just `$^T`, it still works, and you save 4 bytes.

Comment: @chris You obviously have more memory than I do. Still, I'll take your suggestion since there are reasonable computers on which it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <strike>39</strike> <strike>38</strike> 37 bytes

```bash
sed s/[0-9]/duck\\n/g<<<$RANDOM\goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RaFYP9pA1zJWP6U0OTsmJk8/3cbGRiXI0c/F3zcmPT@/OPX/fwA)

Prints a number of ducks equal to the number of digits in an integer uniformly distributed on [0,32767] (so, more often than not, five ducks (a good number of ducks)).

-1 byte each thanks to @Chris and @sch pointing out pairs of quotes that weren't pulling their weight.

Comment: That’s a good number of ducks. :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! Been lurking for a while but this seemed like an easy one to start with. :)

Comment: You can save one byte by getting rid of the single quotes as long as you replace `\n` with `\\n`.

Comment: Nice idea.  You can [do something similar](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BSaU6yNHPxd9XX99eP6U0OZurVik9P7849f9/AA) with just bash constructs and no sed for 30 bytes.

Comment: `sed s/[0-9]/duck\\n/g<<<$RANDOM\goose` can shave off one byte

Comment: Ah! Thank you, @DigitalTrauma. I had played around with using that sort of parameter expansion, but I couldn't get it to replace globally because I didn't know about starting it with a double forward slash. I've been using Bash for about a month now so this is all very educational. Feel free to post yours as a separate answer; it deserves my upvotes! And thank you sch and Chris for the extra bytes.

Comment: @SophiaLechner Ok, thanks, [here it is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158029/11259)

Comment: The `sed` isn't entirely portable. On some platforms you might get away with a single backslash in `\n`. On others you won't get a newline no matter what you do.

Comment: @OlivierDulac suggested using `$$` instead of `$RANDOM` for my answer.  I think you could use the same to save you 5 bytes.

Comment: Have you gotten to testing @DigitalTrauma's suggestion?

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
cat(rep("duck
",rexp(1)+1),"goose")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMotUBDKaU0OZtLSacotaJAw1BT21BTRyk9P784VUnz/38A)

`rexp()` produces a random number from an exponential decay function. `+1` to ensure at least one duck. All lines after the first include a leading space (which is the default separator for `cat`) but this is allowed.

Comment: The probability of outputting more than one duck is `exp(-1)` or around 36.8%.

Comment: It asks to print it on each line. I think you should add " \n" to your "duck"

Comment: @stuartstevenson Here I have used a literal newline rather than `\n` as it is one byte shorter. If you visit the "Try it online!" link you can see that the effect is the same.

Comment: On a DOS/Windows box, that newline would still be two (2) bytes. 0x0d0a

Answer (score 10):

## Pure Bash (no external utilities), 25

Based on [@SophiaLechner's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157940/11259), this also prints *a good number of ducks*.

@OlivierDulac's idea to use the script shell PID as stored in the `$` parameter saves 5 bytes.

```bash
echo "${$//?/duck
}"goose
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BSaVaRV/fXj@lNDmbq1YpPT@/OPX/fwA).

Comment: if we assume you launch a program, it will get a different pid every time. a lot of the time it will be 5 digits long, but not always. hence: change `RANDOM` to `$` to shave 5 bytes?And one could also do a very long string of ducks: `yes duck|head -n $$;echo goose`

Comment: @OlivierDulac yes, I think using `$$` is acceptable - thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! I posted my other version (`yes duck | head -n $$;echo goose`) as an alternative (longer than yours, but one gets a LOT of ducks for 5 extra chars ^^)

Answer (score 9):

## Bash + Coreutils, <s>36</s> 27 bytes

```
yes duck|sed $$q;echo goose
```

Prints too many ducks (between 2 and `cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`), then one goose.

Saved nine bytes thanks to Digital Trauma and Olivier Dulac.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzK1WCGlNDm7pjg1RUFFpdA6NTkjXyE9P7849f9/AA) (but keep in mind that it may get truncated occasionally)

Same length, but with no `echo`:

```
yes duck|sed $${agoose'
q}'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzK1WCGlNDm7pjg1RUFFpToxPT@/OFWdq7BW/f9/AA)

`a` is the append command in `sed`, and `q` quits. Both only run on the line `$$`, which corresponds to the PID.

Comment: Bash has modulo, though that will increase the size. Try `head -n $((1+(RANDOM % 5)))`

Comment: @tripleee Since this is code golf, increasing the size of the output is preferable to increasing that size of the code. And 132767 ducks is downright reasonable compared to the billion or more you see elsewhere ;)

Comment: Sure, just hoping to be helpful in case somebody actually wants to apply this groundbreaking research in practice one day. Like, [TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzK1WCGlNDm7JiM1MUVBN09FQ8NQWyPI0c/F31fVVFNT0zo1OSNfIT0/vzj1/38A). 44 bytes with some spaces taken out.

Comment: @OlivierDulac suggested using `$$` instead of `$RANDOM` for [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158029/11259).  I think you could use the same to save you 5 bytes.  Oh and try `sed` too: `yes duck|sed 1$$q;echo goose`

Comment: In fact `yes duck|sed $$q;echo goose` is fine - I don't think your script would ever get a PID < 1.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma `$$` is a little iffy, since running it twice in the same shell gives the same results. Though it works on TIO, so I guess that's fine? Thanks!

Comment: oh my... I didn't knew there was another answer with the same idea I got.. I'll delete mine and give you an upvote. replace `head -n $$` by `sed $$q` (idea is from @DigitalTrauma)

Comment: @Chris I think for the purposes of codegolf you may assume that the script is saved in a file and run like `./duckgoose.sh`.  In which case it will run in its own shell (with a fresh PID)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Ah, that is true, and makes it much less iffy. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
puts"duck
"*rand(1..9)+"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgppTQ5m0tJqygxL0XDUE/PUlNbKT0/vzhV6f9/AA)

Note: really 31 bytes without the `\n` cheat.

Comment: I’m not sure it’s a cheat, strictly speaking.

Comment: maybe you could do `*(1/rand)` to [shed 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgppTQ5m0tJS8NQvygxL0VTWyk9P784Ven/fwA). this could fail in the case `rand` returns `0.0`, but that seems astronomically unlikely. or well, i tried `100_000_000.times { puts 'zero!' if rand.zero? }` and didn't get a zero, so i'd be OK to deploy this to prod :)

(sorry, i deleted a previous comment unintentionally while trying to edit it)

Comment: @epidemian [Answers with extremely small chances of malfunctioning are not allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13644/46076)

Answer (score 8):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>35</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```powershell
,"duck"*((Random)+1)
"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0cppTQ5W0lLQyMoMS8lP1dBNzdRwVRT21CTSyk9P784Ven/fwA) (modified version)

Generates an array of [`Get-Random`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random?view=powershell-6) number of items. It might take a while. This adds a `+1` to ensure we get at least one `duck`. The modified version also includes a `-ma`ximum flag of `5` so you can see the program works as expected (the modified version will print 1, 2, 3, or 4 `duck`s before the `goose`).

The array and the solitary `goose` string is left on the pipeline, and the implicit `Write-Output` gives us newline-separated values for free.

You don't know how difficult it was for me to not change the last line to ["gray duck"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose#Duck,_Duck,_Gray_Duck) ...

Comment: That variant sounds pretty fun, and definitely worth a code challenge... I recommend you wait a couple of days and post it as a challenge of your own :)

Comment: @AdmBorkBork, this Minnesotan joined this group to just +1 your gray duck.

Comment: `0..(random)|%{'duck'};'goose'` looks like a 29, and will also generate somewhere up to [int]::MaxValue (2.1 billion) ducks before a goose. (And `0..0` does print a duck)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks, but I just-now came up with a 28-byte version. :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
from random import*
print"duck\n"*randint(1,9)+"goose"
```

**[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVKKWUJmfH5ClpgSSBfA1DHUtNbaX0/PziVKX//wE)**

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

```
"duck"ẉ4ṙ0∧"goose"w∨↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9icmFjaHlsb2cy//8iZHVjayLhuok04bmZMOKIpyJnb29zZSJ34oio4oaw//8)

In celebration of the [Language of the month](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14917/language-of-the-month-for-march-2018-brachylog), my first brachylog post. The control flow in this language is cool.

How it works:

```
"duck"ẉ4ṙ0∧"goose"w∨↰
"duck"ẉ                 print duck with a new line
       4ṙ               choose a random number in the range is [0, 4]
         0              verify it equals zero
          ∧             and (short circuits)
           "goose"w     print goose without a newline
                   ∨    or (if it did not equal zero)
                    ↰   repeat the procedure
```

Comment: So, if I’m reading this right, it reads from left-to-right, bottom-to-top?

Comment: The language attempts to find a logical truth using just the first line of the program.  My program says "Validate the second line, then print goose".  Then the second line says "print duck, then validate either a random number 0 to 4 is 0, or validate this line again", so technically left to right just the top line, then any predicates you call from there

Comment: Cool, it’s so interesting finding out how new languages work. It did reach my inbox, but I’m not sure if it’s because I posed the question or because I’d already commented here.

Comment: You can merge the two predicates [like this](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9icmFjaHlsb2cy//8iZHVjayLhuok04bmZMOKIpyJnb29zZSJ34oio4oaw//8) and tie me.

Answer (score 6):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 55 bytes

```cs
Write("{"+new Random().Next(2)+"}{0}goose","duck\n","")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFVDqVpJOy@1XCEoMS8lP1dDU88vtaJEw0hTW6m22qA2PT@/OFVJRymlNDk7Jg/IUNL8/x8A)

Comment: Really clever use of string formatting!

Answer (score 6):

### [Geometry Dash World 2.2 Editor](https://www.google.com/search?q=gdw+2.2+editor&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS698US698&oq=gdw+2.2+editor&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.6191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - 4 objects

[image: Picture of Geometry Dash Level]

**Explanation:**

The BG trigger is the current 2.2's random trigger, so it either toggles the Group ID 1 or 2.

The first "DUCK" has a group id of 1, which makes it have a 50% chance of being removed or not (toggled).

There is no object with the Group ID 2 in this level, so there is a 50% chance of 2 "DUCK"s being displayed.

**How to Reproduce this:**

The first "DUCK" has a Group ID of 1.

[image]

Goose and 2nd duck don't have a Group ID
[image]

Inside the random trigger.
[image]

Comment: I sense a theme for this challenge

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart What?

Comment: There are submissions for Word of Warcraft, Minecraft, and some other game as well.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Better find more games to answer in

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
'Ðœ₁Ωи`.•zíΘ•»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f/fCEo5MfNTWeW3lhR4Leo4ZFVYfXnpsBpA/t/v8fAA)

Will print 2, 5 or 6 ducks and then goose.

-1 byte thanks to @Emigna using ' for a single compressed word (duck)

Comment: You can use `'Ðœ` since duck is a single word.

Comment: Beats mine: `['ÐœTΩ#].•zíΘ•»`

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn I really like your infinite loop approach. Your answer is definitely more in the spirit of the challenge (or what it should have been ?) since it can output an infinite amount of ducks.

Comment: @Kaldo still, 15 bytes loses to yours ;)

Comment: Alternate 14-byter: `'Ðœ₁Ω.D.•zíΘ•»`

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @EriktheOutgolfer*

```apl
'Goose'⍪⍨(?9)5⍴'Duck '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X909P784Vf1R76pHvSs07C01TR/1blF3KU3OVlDHLwsA)

Comment: Alternative: `'Goose'⊣⎕←⍣(?9)⊢'Duck'`

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>31</s> 22 bytes

```
"duck"a>x
r"esoog"<>o<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XymlNDlbKdGugqtIKbU4Pz9dycYu3@b/fwA)

-9 bytes based on Not a tree's revision

Comment: You could remove `l?!;` and exit with an error.

Comment: And you could save some more like [this](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0FBKbU4Pz9dqYyrwkYppTQ5WynRhssu//9/AA)

Comment: Or like [this](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XymlNDlbKdGugqtIKbU4Pz9dSd8u3@b/fwA).

Comment: @Notatree I get that one to sometimes print "\nkcud\nkcud...". It rarely behaves correctly

Comment: @Suppen Just using an arrow instead of a mirror fixes it; see edit.

Comment: @KSmarts Aargh, sent the wrong link, well done for fixing it…

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 17 bytes

```
?\\K`duck
K`goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3z4mxjshpTQ5m8s7IT0/vzj1/38A)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P8Y7IaU0OZvLXjvGPYHLOyE9P7849f9/AA)

Prints 1 or 2 ducks, with equal probability.

#### Explanation

```
?\\K`duck
```

Set the working string to `duck` and print it with a trailing linefeed (`\`). Then this is wrapped in another output stage, but this one has the random flag (`?`) applied to it, so it only prints with a probability of 50%.

```
K`goose
```

Replace the `duck` with `goose`, which is printed implicitly at the end of the program.

Here's a fun alternative which prints 1 duck with 50% probability, 2 ducks with 25%, 3 ducks with 12.5%...:

```
\K`duck
?+\G`
K`goose
```

Answer (score 5):

## Vim (script) on Linux, <del>46</del> 43 bytes (<del>49</del> 46 with `:` at start of line)

```
.!date +0\%N\%s6
s/6.*/goose
s/\d/duck\r/g
```

Executed as `vim -S filename` or pasted into running `vim` with `:` before each line.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You should be able to use `\d` over `[0-9]`. Also, it looks like vim doesn't require the trailing newline, so this can be 45 bytes :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 5):

## [Befunge 98](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html), <s>38</s> <s>30</s> 25 bytes

```
"esooG"v>:#,_@
"Duck"a<?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9XSi3Oz3dXKrOzUtaJd@BScilNzlZKtLG3@f8fAA)

- Thanks @JoKing for stripping the useless trampoline
- Switching to Befunge 98 for shorter new line - now `Duck` fits within a single string

Comment: You don't need the `#` on the second line

Comment: And "technically", `whitespace within a line is fine` so you can cut out a couple of quotes (even if the output looks weird)

Comment: @JoKing Thanks, see my edit.

Answer (score 5):

## [T-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference), <s>70 44</s> 43 bytes (Many ducks)

```
while rand()<.9print'duck'print'duck
goose'
```

Thanks @Zac Faragher!

### Revised Version, <s>54 43</s> 40 bytes (1 or 2 ducks)

Thanks @BradC!

```
if rand()<.5print'duck'print'duck
goose'
```

I can't seem to get this to run properly in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15ff7/4), but it works just fine in LINQPad and SSMS.

Not sure if this is a known limitation of SQL Fiddle or I'm just doing something wrong

Comment: Nice. Down to 61 if you change `select` to `print` and replace the final `'duck'select'goose'` with `'duck(linebreak)goose'` (with a literal linebreak, of course)

Comment: Actually, you can just do `while rand()<.5print'duck'print'duck(linebreak)goose'` for 43.

Comment: Nice, thanks @BradC. Is there another way to represent a line break in a string other than adding a char(13)?

Comment: Yep, just literally put a return inside the quotes, I'll edit your post to show you (comments don't show returns).

Comment: Save 3 more bytes: change the first `while` to `if`. Prints (randomly) either one duck or two, which (I believe) still satisfies the challenge.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of it that way. 1 or 2 ducks is technically random...

Comment: you can trim out the begin/end from the original answer for 46 bytes if you use linebreaks properly. That way it can still print more than 2 ducks
`while(rand()<.5)[br]print'duck'[br]print'duck[br]goose'`

Comment: @Alex looks like you can still trim a byte from the first answer: `while rand()<.5print'duck'print'duck[br]goose'`

Answer (score 5):

## Powershell - <s>31</s> 30 bytes

**Warning**: You're most likely going to end up with a lot of ducks. `Random` includes the values of 0 to `Int32.MaxValue` so, depending on how random you're number is, this could be a lot of quacking.

```
1..(Random)|%{"Duck"};"Goose"
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `$` in front of `(Random)`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPTyMoMS8lP1dBNzdRwVSzRrVayaU0OVup1lrJPT@/OFXp/38A "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @AdmBorkBork thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 4):

## [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), <s>24</s> 19 bytes

```
R"duck"N#
"goose"*[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7Mz/v/P0gppTQ5W8lPmUspPT@/OFVJK/r/fwA)

-5 bytes thanks to Martin Ender

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript <s>79</s> <s>69</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

*-10 bits thanks to @Herman Lauenstein*

*-7 bits thanks to @binarymax*

*-2 bits thanks to @Shaggy*

```
_=>{for(_=0;_++<=new Date%9;)(l=console.log)`Duck`;l`goose`}
```

```js
a=_=>{for(_=0;_++<=new Date%9;)(l=console.log)`Duck`;l`goose`}
a()
```

Comment: 69 bytes: `_=>{for(_=0;_<Math.random()*9;_++)(l=console.log)('Duck');l('goose')}`

Comment: Won't this give you no ducks if `random` returns zero?

Comment: 63 Bytes: ```_=>{for(_=0;_<=new Date%10;_++)(l=console.log)`Duck`;l`goose`}```

Comment: @binarymax, you can save 2 more bytes on that with `_++<=new Date%9` and a few more by using `alert` instead of `console.log`.

Comment: Or you can use my original solution for 42 bytes: `while(alert'duck',new Date%9);alert'goose'` (replace single quotes with backticks).

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, but i would prefer having a different answer than yours. Although yours is better

Comment: You're more than welcome to it; my solution is now significantly different.

Comment: One byte shorter: `for(_=9;_-->new Date%9;)`. Another four bytes less: `for(_=new Date;_--;)` (no idea if that works, though)

Comment: ``(_=0)=>{for(l=console.log;_++<=new Date%9;)l`Duck`;l`goose`}`` <-- made it cleaner

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html)

<s>57</s> 35 bytes (perimeter of the entire field is <s>19x3</s> 17x2 charachters) Thanks to karhell for the improvement.

```
55+"kcud",,,,,#v?
  @,,,,,"goose"<
```

The second line puts duck and a newline on the stack (backwards) and outputs it as a string. After that 75% chance of going back to the start and printing duck again, 25% (when question mark decides to go down) to print goose and stop.

Comment: If a 50% chance to goose is acceptable, `55+"kcud",,,,,#v?(linebreak here)  
  @,,,,,"goose"< ` would cut your code down to 35 bytes

Comment: Ah the sweet wrap-around. You're right, thanks, I'll post an update later!

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 21 bytes

```
1ṙ+₁;"Duck
"j₍,"Goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3/Dhzpnaj5oarZVcSpOzuZSyHjX16ii55@cXp/7//z8KAA)

Hey, language of the month going inactive, let's kick things up a little!

Answer (score 4):

## Minecraft Functions (18w11a, 1.13 snapshots), <s>402</s> 382 bytes

[image: duck duck goose in minecraft]

Uses three functions in the `minecraft` namespace

a:

```
scoreboard objectives add r custom:play_one_minute
scoreboard objectives add t dummy
scoreboard objectives add x dummy
scoreboard players set @s t 9
scoreboard players operation @s x = @s r
scoreboard players operation @s x %= @s t
function b
```

b:

```
execute if score @s x = @s t run say Goose
execute unless score @s x = @s t run function c
```

c:

```
say Duck
scoreboard players add @s x 1
function b
```

[Datapack with the functions](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_qS_l4TQtjhamOkoLc3EobsZrJlPVDQ8)

-20 bytes by removing unnecessary namespaces

## Explanation

Function `a` creates three scoreboard objectives (variables). Objectives with the criteria `dummy` are like conventional variables, however, `r` has the criteria 
 `custom:play_one_minute`. This means it will increase each in game minute. By using modulus it becomes a pseudorandom number between 0 and 9.  The `t` objective is used because there is no way to do math with literal values, so we need a "constant" objective.

The function `b` is the main loop, calling the `c` function until the counter objective `x` is equal to 9 at which point it prints "Goose".

The `c` function prints "Duck", increments the counter objective and then calls the `b` function again

Comment: Nice work, I [approve of Minecraft submissions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124049/display-random-colored-pixels/124610#124610). Can you explain how this generates a variable number of ducks?

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes

```r
while({cat("duck
");rt(1,1)>0})0;cat('goose')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMydVozo5sURDKaU0OZtLSdO6qETDUMdQ086gVtPAGiSjnp6fX5yqrvn/PwA)

Outgolfed by [@user2390246](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157897/code-golf-duck-duck-goose/157920#157920)

Prints a single `duck`, then with probability `1/2`, prints another duck and repeats, or prints `goose` and terminates.

This could also be without the `>0` part, since the Student's `t`-distribution might eventually return a `0` but that is highly improbable, so I prefer this.

Comment: [35 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKMotUBDKaU0OZtLSacotaJAw1BT21BTRyk9P784VUnz/38A)

Comment: @user2390246 I think that's sufficiently different from mine as to warrant its own answer, especially since _every_ answer is bound to be a variant of "generate a random number of ducks one goose"; yours is a quite distinct approach.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for your sportsmanship! Added as a [separate answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157920/66252)

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, <s>31</s> 25 bytes

```
?"duck
EXEC!RND(9)?"goose
```

Has a 1/9 chance of ending after each iteration.

### Explanation:

```
PRINT "duck"
EXEC !RND(9)
PRINT "goose"
```

SmileBasic has 4 "slots" that you can run code in. Normally programs run in slot 0, but you can load things like libraries into the others.
`EXEC <slot>` is used to run code in a different slot.

`RND(9)` generates a random number from 0 to 8. If this is 0, `!RND(9)` is 1, otherwise it's 0.

`EXEC 0` will run the current slot from the beginning (creating a loop), but `EXEC 1` runs slot 1 (which is empty)

After running slot 1, execution returns to slot 0, and the program prints "goose" and ends.

Answer (score 3):

## DOS .BAT, 54 Bytes

```
@for /l %%d in (0,9,%random%)do @echo duck
@echo goose
```

## 43 Bytes

```
[main.bat]
  @0&echo goose
[0.bat]
  @echo duck&%random% 2>nul
```

Comment: Change the `1` to a `0` in case `%random%` returns 0?

Comment: @Neil       Done　　　　　　　　　　　　　　

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

prints `1` to `256` ducks.

```python
import os
print("duck\n"*-~os.urandom(1)[0]+"goose")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCG/mKugKDOvREMppTQ5OyZPSUu3Lr9Yr7QoMS8lP1fDUDPaIFZbKT0/vzhVSfP/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

Prints 1 or 2 ducks

```
`goo `i`Ýõ
`pM¬Ä
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YGdvb6BgaWDd9QpgcE2sxA==&input=)

Saved 1 byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) & 1 byte thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver)

#### Explanation

```
`goo `     // compressed string "goose"
      i    // prepend string
       `Ýõ // compressed string "duck\n"
`          // ...
 p         // repeat n times
  M¬       // random int 0 or 1
    Ä      // add 1
```

Comment: [17 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YGdvb6BgaWDd9QpgcE1xIMQ=&input=)

Comment: [16 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=YGdvb6BgaWDd9QpgcE2sxA==&input=)

Comment: You can use `p2â ö` to randomly return `1` or `2`. Unfortunately the shortcut for `p2` wouldn't be useful here so it would still be 17 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver! I didn't catch that in the shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dirty](https://github.com/Ourous/dirty), 20 bytes

*Warning: May produce up to 2^63 "duck"s*

```
#.⇖('duck'‼)'goose'‼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8ksKqn8/19Z71H7NA31lNLkbPVHDXs01dPz84tTQcz//wE)

**Explained:**

```
#.⇖       generate a range up to a random number, put into left stack
('duck'‼) while left stack isn't empty, print "duck" and a newline
'goose'‼  print "goose" and a newline
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim + `date`, <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```
:r!date +1\%SO␊D@"duck␛ogoose
```

Prints 100 to 159 ducks

### Explanation

```
:r!date +1\%SO␊        Get the current date in seconds, prepend it with and postpend an O
D@"aduck␛             Take the current line, cut it and use as code to insert duck the
                       specified amount of times
ogoose                 insert goose
```

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 35 bytes

```php
duck
<?=time()%2?'duck
':''?>
goose
```

Or rand() if you prefer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/pTQ5m8vG3rYkMzdVQ1PVyF4dLKJupa5ub8eVnp9fnPr/PwA)

Comment: I think this breaks the rule "There must be exactly one bird on each line. No empty lines."

Comment: @Goose: There is a leading duck in the first line before the code.

Comment: Save one byte with `-n` and `date(s)` instead of `time()%2`.

Comment: @Tinus there's nothing in this code to makes new lines. Everything is on the same line. Every duck and goose must be on it's own line.

Comment: @Goose works for me

Comment: @Οurous I see my mistake, whoops

Comment: You can save another byte by putting `goose` on the same line as `?>` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/pTQ5m8vG3rYkMzdVQ1PVyF4dLKJupa5ub5een1@c@v8/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
print("duck\n"^rand(1:9),"goose")
```

This will print `duck` up to 9 times before `goose`!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/oCgzr0RDKaU0OTsmTymuKDEvRcPQylJTRyk9P784VUnz/38A)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can include a link to [Try it online! (aka TIO)](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUz8/7@gKDOvREMppTQ5OyZPKa4oMS9Fw9DKUlNHKT0/vzhVSfP/fwA) for your answer; TIO has a lot of interpreters and can automatically format your answer for you :)

Answer (score 3):

## F#, 74 bytes

```
let c=System.Random().Next()
for i=0 to c do
 printfn"duck"
printfn"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/Pye1RCHZNriyuCQ1Vy8oMS8lP1dDU88vtaJEw8hAkystv0gh09ZAoSRfIVkhJZ9LoaAoM68kLU8ppTQ5W4kLxkvPzy9OVfr/HwA) - but note that the sample is limited to at most 20 ducks.

Setting i=0 means that if c is 0, then at least one "duck" will still be printed.

Comment: Why using variable c and not just `for i=0 to System.Random().Next()do printfn"duck"` directly?

Comment: It would interfere with the randomness of it. Instead of i terminating at a random value, the larger i gets the more chance it has of being greater than a new random value.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 44 bytes

```sql
a:PRINT'duck'IF RAND()<.5GOTO a PRINT'goose'
```

Different method than [Alex' excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157897/duck-duck-goose/158023#158023).

Answer (score 3):

## *Pure* Bash, <del>41</del> 37 bytes

```
printf %s\\n ${RANDOM//[0-9]/duck } goose
```

This uses the same trick as in [Sophia Lechner's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157940/33187) to obtain a random number in the range 0-32767 with `$RANDOM` but does not require `sed` or *any* other external utilities to be installed to transform it into the desired result.

The Bash parameter expansion `${variable//pattern/replacement}` obtains the value of `variable` with any match on `pattern` replaced by `replacement`.  The shell then expands and tokenizes the arguments to `printf`, which applies the format string to each resulting argument.

I'm not a good golfer. [Digital Trauma's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158029/33187) has a much more lenient `pattern` which gets me down to 37 bytes.

```
printf %s\\n ${RANDOM//?/duck } goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1OCYmT0GlOsjRz8XfV1/fXj@lNDlboVYhPT@/OPX/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 36 bytes:

```php
<?do{?>duck
<?}while(date(s))?>goose
```

Run with `-n` (no config file)

Answer (score 3):

## **Forth, 91 BYTES**

```
: DUCKDUCKGOOSE BEGIN 0 100 RANDOM 0 = IF ." GOOSE " LEAVE ELSE ." DUCK " THEN CR UNTIL ;
```

**OUTPUT: **

```
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
DUCK 
GOOSE  ok....
```

Comment: Technically you need to add `include random.fs` also you can make it [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##Tcs7DsIwEATQPqcY3CdKWjgBFQ0ljWWvwwpnF/mjCC5viEJBNaOnmaCp3Ps5bNEai4vVE5IVr8sQcndEwDSOP0E/wSsGA1/dw8AlRNXnBrNqJoNTq4UXgk9fzkQeh///DdfzBTVThhGVfmezL7NiJchWi4KFC9vIbwIXLFaqjfHVhfYB) by using a do loop

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 23 bytes

```
25*"kcud"#@,,,,,"goose?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/38hUSyk7uTRFSdlBBwSU0vPzi1Pt//8HAA)

Starts by printing "duck\n". The only way to generate randomness is with the `?` instruction, which sets the PC's direction to one of the 4 possible directions, chosen at random. Up/down will wrap around vertically right back to the `?` instruction, right will wrap around and print "duck\n" again, and left will print "goose" and terminate the program. The worst-case runtime is infinite, but the probability of the program exiting is 1.

With this code layout, we can reuse `,,,,,` to print either string - luckily they are both of length 5. We can also omit the `"` after `goose`, which makes the stack leak with stringified code, but otherwise leaves it in a workable state, and all of the letters from the strings are practically no-ops when executed as code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
from random import*
while random():print"duck"
print"duck\ngoose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocZVnZOakQgU1NK0KijLzSpRSSpOzlbgQ7Ji89Pz84lSl//8B)

-6 bytes thanks to Rod

theoretically finishes. practically will probably never finish but eventually `random.random()` will spit out a 0

Comment: I've not seen it finishing after a few tries... Theoretically it will is a fun one, tho ;)

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocZVnZOakQgU1NK0KijLzSpRSSpOzlbgQ7Ji89Pz84lSl//8B)

Comment: I'm not totally certain this is valid, isn't it possible that for some seed the PRNG will actually never generate a zero? It's not a particularly big deal, since you can correct it easily, but I think this would technically need a proof.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I think in this case "Never say never" is mathematically accurate.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>66</s> <s>65</s> <s>53</s> 50 bytes

```c
main(){for(;puts("duck")&time(0););puts("goose");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6Lb9Iw7qgtKRYQymlNDlbSVOtJDM3VcNA01oTKpyen1@cqqRpXfv/PwA)

Comment: I can print one or two ducks in 46 bytes if you're interested...

Comment: @Neil Post your answer

Comment: `main(){puts("duck\nduck\ngoose"+time(0)%2*5);}`

Comment: I think as `puts` returns `5` all the time (for this case), so `for(;time(0)&puts("duck");)` may work (although in a different way)

Comment: If you use `puts("duck")&time(0)` u should say the environment. Some `puts()` return 0

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

<sup>Turns out [thecoder16 ninja'd](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157917/53748) this Python 2 version...</sup>

```python
from random import*
print"duck\n"*randint(1,9)+"goose"
```

Prints 1-9 `duck`s then a `goose`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVKKWUJmfH5ClpgSSBfA1DHUtNbaX0/PziVKX//wE)**

---

Originally...

[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>61</s>  56 bytes

```python
from random import*
print("duck\n"*randint(1,9)+"goose")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaCillCZnx@QpaYFkQQKGOpaa2krp@fnFqUqa//8DAA)

Comment: You can reach [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVKKWUJmfH5ClpgSSBfA1DHUtNbaX0/PziVKX//wE) if you switch to py2

Comment: I think I may have just posted that, sorry

Comment: @thecoder16 Oh you ninja'd me? :D

Comment: It’s down there somewhere, about 3 minutes ago, though it’s not properly formatted because I don’t know how :( Should I delete or what?

Comment: @thecoder16 No, that's fine, I've hit the same solution as others within short time frames before - I only delete if I am much later and it's just a result of not reading other answers! (I've also linked to your post too)

Answer (score 2):

## [FORTRAN 77](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/index.html), <s>121</s> 120 bytes

```
      PROGRAM D
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(A)
      DO1WHILE I=1,A*9+1
1     PRINT*,'DUCK'
      PRINT*,'GOOSE'
      END
```

Prints up to <s>ten</s> nine ducks (thanks AdmBorkBork!).

Unfortunately, there is no syntax highlighting for Fortran. I can't understand why, since it is so popular and useful!

(Saved 11 bytes changing the Do-While syntax. Oh, such versatility!)

This program could have 92 bytes changing all the spaces in the indentation for tabs; it works using compiler `gfortran`, but I'm not sure it would work in older compilers. Since *original* FORTRAN 77 only accept spaces (because the punched card thing), I decided to not use tabs. Anyway, thanks Pavel for the suggestion!

---

## [FORTRAN 77](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/index.html), 132 bytes

```
      PROGRAM D
      CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(A)
      DO 1,I=1,A*10+1
      PRINT*,'DUCK'
1     CONTINUE
      PRINT*,'GOOSE'
      END
```

Comment: Can you use tabs for indentation to save bytes?

Comment: I'm afraid Fortran 77 do not accept tabs, since the first columns in each line are reserved for labels, e.g., as you can see in the fifth line. Tabs are accepted (with warnings) since Fortran 90.

Comment: Can you save a byte using `A*9` instead of `A*10`?

Comment: Wow, I'm ashamed! Pretty clever! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep to comment on the other PowerShell answer, so I have to post it separately:

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 36 bytes

```powershell
,'duck'*(random -mi 1 -ma 9);'goose'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0c9pTQ5W11LoygxLyU/V0E3N1PBEEgmKlhqWqun5@cXp6r//w8A)

My answer is longer, because the maximum flag is required. Omitting it often leads to an OutOfMemoryException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range. In this case the program does not output anything besides the error.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>83</s> <s>82</s> <s>72</s> <s>68</s> <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```java
v->(Math.random()<.5?"duck\n":"")+"duck\ngoose"
```

Returns either one or two `"duck"` before `"goose"`.

-1 byte thanks to *@l4m2*.
-4 bytes thanks to *@someone*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwEEX3fsWkqzbG7tyIjy@AjYkbdTGWioUyJbSQGMO31xJIZhZ3Jjn31DjiznWa6rKJyqL3kKOh3wbAUND9G5WGYo4A19AbqkDxmzMljCJL1yltGh8wGAUFEJwgjrszzzF8ZI9UupaLo9xfWDmo5kHswJjYrqFyzmsWswXSDS@bICtrnEva5MKX3vsTxerx9UG30g1BdukTLHGSitNgrVilpvgH)

```java
v->                   // Method with empty unused parameter and String return-type
  (Math.random()<.5?  //  If the random boolean is true:
    "duck\n"          //   Return a "duck" + new-line
   :                  //  Else:
    "")               //   Return nothing
   +"duck\ngoose";    //  Appended with a "duck", new-line and "goose"
```

Comment: `d+=.1` => `d*=2`

Comment: I made several searches before posting my answer, but I couldn't find this one, for some reason. I deleted it after seeing this one. Anyways, I'm not sure this fulfills the challenge as the challenge specifies "print", not "output". Edit... 2 pages, that's why I didn't see it...

Comment: "_Anyways, I'm not sure this fulfills the challenge as the challenge specifies "print", not "output"._" Well, it also specifies program instead of function. I personally interpret 'print' as 'print or return' in almost all cases, except for explicitly STDOUT is mentioned. But maybe that's just me..

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but this seems to work for [47 bytes.](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoIwEIZ3n@LSqY2hm4tEfAJZTFzU4SwVC@VKaEtiDM@OJZDcDf9d8v1fgyNmrtfUVO2sLHoPFzT02wEYCnp4o9JQLhHgGgZDNSh@c6aCUeTpOqVN4wMGo6AEghPMY1bwC4aPHJAq13FRyMOZVVG1D2JHxsR@C7VzXrM5XyF9fNkE2VjjUtIlF7723p8oNo@vD7qTLgbZp0@wxEkqTtFasUlN8x8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online") According to the docs, Math.random() returns values such that 0 *<=* x < 1, so Math.random()>0 should work too, but that seems hard to test and very unlikely to actually happen.

Comment: @someone The changes of an actual `0.000...` are indeed astronomical small. But your 47-byte version is indeed a nice golf, so thanks! :)

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5PD4IwDMXvfopmpy0G7op/Dp7lYuJFPcxtwmB0hG0YY/jsOISkTfPa9L1fxXue2FZhJetRGO4cnLnG7wpAo1fdiwsF@SQBLr7TWICgV6sl9CyL2yF2rBwQ9jD2yYGW3JUnKxVlu82RyCDqO5ItIWy9iMJap8iYzZ9teBotwHnu4@gn5yYC0Dns9uBsCf84r5rUBp@28eINUlTvPyxlKaaCYjCGLVDD@AM "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online") seems to work for 43 bytes, but it requires creation of a instance Main and has a similar(i?)ly low chance of ducking twice, but it at least happens in a tight loop.

Comment: @someone I'm afraid `hashCode()` will always give the same result for this class; [`1418481495` in this case](https://tio.run/##RY7NDoIwEITvPsWmpzaGclb8OXiWi4kX9VBLlULZElowxvDsWITEZDebmUl2vkJ0IrK1wiIrB2mEc3AUGj8LAI1eNQ8hFaSjBDj5RuMTJD1bnUHHkuD2YcOkgLCFoYt2uXD5wWaKsiUhEMf0b2xWe5K1srwiWRMS8kk8rXWKDMn0qW7vRktwXvhwurGpCkB0Kr/cBJth3s6ritvW8zok3iBF9frBU8aRS4qtMWyG7Icv). So it won't ever be lower than 9 using the default non-overwritten `hashCode`. Nice try though.

Answer (score 2):

## **[Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 22 bytes**

```
9rand)"duck\n"*"goose"
```

Comment: (completely new to golfscript, this may not be optimal)

Answer (score 2):

My name has never been more relevant.

**PHP, 40 bytes**

```
<?=str_repeat("duck\n",date("h"))?>goose
```

Only trick used is `date("h")` to generate a random number that will never be 0.

Comment: Presumably you could just as easily use millisecond?

Comment: Probably a lot of options depending on how wide a range of random numbers you want, but I think they'd all be the same byte count.

Comment: @Goose using `mktime()` saves one byte

Comment: @Ben true, but it tries to allocate 7605159771 bytes and I can't run that on my machine so I'm not sure if it's appropriate to include.

Comment: For the purposes of code golf, you may assume infinite memory.

Comment: default values (no config; flag `-n`) disable notices and allow `<?=str_repeat("duck\n",date(h))?>goose` or `<?=str_repeat("duck\n",date(h)),goose;`, saving two bytes; a literal newline saves another byte.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 57 bytes

```
$r=Random @(1..9)
for($x=0;$x -lt $r;$x++){"Duck"}"Goose"
```

While $x is less than the value of $r, write "duck", else write "goose".

First code golf I've done.  Had fun with the challenge, and am looking forward to getting better!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 17 bytes

```
es"duck
"*"goose"
```

Prints around 10^12 ducks. `es` is the builtin for Unix timestamp.

For two more bytes, a version with more reasonable output:

```
9mr)"duck
"*"goose"
```

Answer (score 2):

### Groovy, 42 bytes

```groovy
print'duck\n'*(1+Math.random()*10)+'goose'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy/Kzy@r/P@/oCgzr0Q9pTQ5OyZPXUvDUNs3sSRDrygxLyU/V0NTy9BAU1s9PT@/OFX9/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 33 bytes

```
=REPT("duck
",9*RAND()+1)&"goose"
```

Prints `duck` between 1 and 10 times, followed by `goose`.

Answer (score 2):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), 43 bytes

```
PRINT REPLICATE('duck
',RAND()*5+1)+'goose'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Assembly (nasm, x64, Linux)](http://www.nasm.us/), <s>79</s> 55 bytes

```
global main

main:
  rdrand ecx
  jnc main
.ducks:
  mov al, 1      ; Move the syscall id into ral. Doing it using a single byte is shorter
  mov edi, eax   ; Copy the value over, which takes exactly 2 bytes.
  xor esi, esi   ; \
  or rsi, duckD  ; Move a pointer to duckD into rsi. This is shorter than the equivalent move.
  mov dl, 5      ; Move the size of the string into rdl.
  push rcx       ; Preserve rcx for use by the loop instruction
  syscall        ; Call the syscall. in this case, syscall write to file descriptor 1, aka stdout.
  pop rcx        ; Restore rcx
  loop .ducks    ; Decrement rcx and jmp back to .ducks if rcx isn't 0
  mov al, 1
  mov edi, eax
  xor esi, esi
  or rsi, gooseD
  mov dl, 6
  syscall
  ret
duckD: db 'duck', 10, 0
gooseD: db 'goose', 10, 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY69DsIwDIT3PIW3LgWVAYbOvIibRKWQnyqmqH36YCdFgpUl@s7n8wWJrB/cdghIPufRxQEdeJyCUvL2CiCZhMGA1SuLe9DVPppFP0h8H1@AroXTztZMLViU7TUmsCSSJpaskiiJXvdtw8kz87zQDVLpoI00OifDOO8zFxlr51@VY4xkvzsvP0XJPlX5VQ9mgEaw4fNdC52q0WoU/jg5vwE)

A simple explanation of syscall write is sitting here. Mostly for me, because I forget it exists sometimes.

WARNING: May print up to 2^32 ducks

Answer (score 2):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 30 bytes

There is a 25% chance after each `duck` that the loop will be broken and `goose` will be printed. This is because the `X` cell, which chooses a random cardinal direction. Every direction except right will skip over the lower segment due to how the `~` are placed.

```
>"kcud"WNojrXv
^~@W"goose"~<>~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/99OKTu5NEUp3C8/qyiijCuuziFcKT0/vzhVqc7Gru7/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> <s>43</s> 33 bytes

```python
print"duck\n"*(id(0)%9+1)+"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKaU0OTsmT0lLIzNFw0BT1VLbUFNbKT0/vzhV6f9/AA)

Takes no input. Prints a max of 9 'duck's.

**Explanation:**

```python
               # Call the id() function on the integer 0.
               # This is a different, usually very large integer every time the program is executed.
               # % 9 will return 0-8, so this will return 1-9.
               id(0)%9+1
# print 1-9 'duck's, each ending in a new line, then finally 'goose'
print"duck\n"*(.........)+"goose"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
-(h)
duck
{~goose|->h}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/q9rl6Fr919XI0OTK6U0OZurui49P784tQYoXvv/PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>17</s> <s>16</s> 15 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
9╒wôÿduckn'g╕3`
```

-1 byte thanks to *@maxb*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/y0dRJ5Ye3HN6fUpqcnaee/mjqVOOE//8B)

**Explanation:**

Prints `[1, 9]` amount of `duck`.

```python
9╒          # Push a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  w         # Pop and push a random integer from this list
   ô        # Loop that many times and execute the following six characters:
    ÿduck   #  Push the 4-character string "duck"
         n  #  Push a newline
   'g╕3`   '# After the loop: push 'g' and compressed "oose"
            # (join everything on the stack together and output it implicitly)
```

Comment: To get a random number in range `[1, 9]` inclusive: `9╒w`. This way, you don't have to discard the stack after the loop. 15-byter: [9╒wôÿduckp'g╕3`](https://tio.run/##ASIA3f9tYXRoZ29sZv//OeKVknfDtMO/ZHVja3AnZ@KVlTNg////)

Comment: @maxb Ah, of course! I initially had `9w`, but of course it could also result in `0`, so I changed it to `fú` and combined it with `╒`, but was kinda annoyed by the integers still on the stack. But of course `9╒w` is better, fixing that problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 25 bytes

```sh
repeat $ <<<duck
<<<goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@K/xvyi1IDWxREFFwcbGJqU0OZsLSKfn5xen/tesKc3LLFTQTf4PAA)

Prints `duck` {process ID} times. A PID is not really random, but it's indeterminate and never 0. On TIO, this tends to be in the region of 10,000.

Comment: I really like that approach to the challenge!

Comment: 10,000? That's a lot of ducks.

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 22 bytes

```
∇P
'DUCK'
→?3
'GOOSE'∇
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 27 bytes

```
"Duck"9`1[p&:09?]p"Goose"&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/1/JpTQ5W8kywTC6QM3KwNI@tkDJPT@/OFVJLf//fwA)

The code pushes a random number of "Duck\n" strings onto a stack, then pushes "Goose" and prints the whole thing.

```
"Duck"                      - push "Duck" onto the stack
      9`                    - push LF (9+1) onto the stack
        1                   - push 1 to start loop
         [p     ]p          - loop until top of stack is "0"
           &:               - duplicate stack
             09?            - generate random number in 0-9 range
                  "Goose"   - push "Goose" on the stack
                         &o - print the entire stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby: 33 bytes

```
puts 'duck\n'*Time.new.sec+'goose'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBPaU0OTsmT10rJDM3VS8vtVyvODVZWz09P784Vf3/fwA) (Note that TIO doesn't respect newline characters like a normal console)

It might take a second, but sooner or later it'll print another number of ducks...

Okay, I just like the idea, it'd be a little shorter as:

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

Shortened thanks to @ovs

```ruby
puts"duck\n"*-~rand(9)+'goose'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgppTQ5OyZPSUu3rigxL0XDUlNbPT0/vzhV/f9/AA)

Comment: Ah, you've bested my Ruby version by a byte! I have had to resort to a cheat to get down to 30 (which if you apply would get you to 29).

Comment: That's 34 bytes, not 33.

Comment: @Shaggy I got there with Ruby’s ‘length’ function. Perhaps it’s reading the newline character as one?

Comment: *Note that TIO doesn't respect newline characters like a normal console* This is not a TIO issue. `\n` works inside double quotes, but not inside single quotes. In any case, `\n` can be replaced with a literal newline. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBPaU0OZtLXSskMzdVLy@1XK84NVlbPT0/vzhV/f9/AA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## J: 24 bytes

Arbitrarily limited to no more than 9 ducks:

```
'Goose',~>(>:?9)$<'Duck'
```

Comment: I've just run this through Try It Online. It doesn't seem to output anything. https://tio.run/##y/r/X909P784VV2nzlrDzsreUlPFRt2lNDlbR0H9/38A

Comment: You need to use `echo` to get the output (presumably this is assumed to be run on the REPL). Try [this](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I19B3T0/vzhVXafOWsPOyt5SU8VG3aU0OVtHQf3/fwA). I don't know why it seems like it only outputs one possible number of "Duck"s, though (probably has to do with the way J evaluates `?` in nouns).

Comment: TIO seems to prescribe a particular format not suited to an immediate execution language like J (or their J implementation is broken).  Try putting the code both in "Code" and "Input".

Comment: J seeds the RNG with `16807` on startup, so the output is always deterministic, noun or not. [Try it with seeding](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlaKNnaGCgVW1lpmhloK6u8D81OSNfQd09P784VV2nzlrDzsreUlPFRt2lNDlbR0H9/38A)

Comment: According to Dennis at the tio site, you need to prefix the J code with "echo" to see the output.  To re-seed the RNG, you could add this phrase to the right of a J phrase using random numbers: `[ 9!:1]<.13#.|.}.6!:0'' `

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 38 bytes

```
loop random 9[print"duck"]print"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmqIQHatQlJiXkp@rX5wK5Obll@uXZOam/s/Jzy@AyihYRhcUZeaVKKWUJmcrxULY6fn5xalK//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>43</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

EDIT: Saved 3 bytes thanks to l4m2

EDIT: Saved 4 bytes by removing useless `end=` from print function.

```
print('Duck\n'*max(id(0),1),'Goose')
```

Python's `id` function produces an indeterminate value between runs of the program. So we call `id` on 0. `id` is not guaranteed to be `>=1`, so use `max` to ensure the value is at least 1.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Is hash guaranteed to be non-zero?  The output is required to have at least one duck.

Comment: @recursive Good point. Edited.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer How so?

Comment: So what about `id(something)`

Comment: @mypetlion The previous version wasn't guaranteed to have a non-zero hash...

Comment: @l4m2 Do you know if `id` is guaranteed positive? I couldn't find any indication one way or the other online.

Comment: http://www.archivum.info/python-dev@python.org/2005-02/00414/Re-(Python-Dev)-builtin_id()-returns-negative-numbers.html

Comment: 29 bytes using python2: `print'Duck\n'*-~id(0)+'Goose'`

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 24 bytes

```
⊃((?⎕),1)/'duck' 'goose'
```

Prompts for an integer which can be between 1 and system maximum and will then select a number from 1 to that integer at random for the number of ducks. If no input is desired then the max integer can be hard coded for a few more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP <s>53</s> 45 bytes

```
echo str_repeat("duck\n",rand(1,99))."goose";
```

*-8 bits thanks to @manatwork*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4ArNTkjX6G4pCi@KLUgNbFEQymlNDk7Jk9JpygxL0XDUMfSUlNTTyk9P784Vcmay97u/38A)

Comment: Wouldn't `rand(1,99)` do essentially the same as `substr(rand(),-2)`?

Comment: @manatwork yep, didn't know that function existed, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Aceto](https://github.com/aceto/aceto) with `-l` flag, 25 bytes

```
R99**i"duck\n"*£p"goose"p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOLcn//z/I0lJLK1MppTQ5OyZPSevQ4gKl9Pz84lSlgv///@UXlGTm5xX/180BAA)

Comment: Command-line flags are [counted as separate languages, now](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/42963), so no need to add +1 to your byte count.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Wasn't aware. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 68 bytes

Uses flag `-w`.
(Turns out we've decided to [simplify how we count flags](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339).)

```
!
>----z/v\ZZZZZt
>ZZZZ-xL')))xc
xx)))b`? b(((
)x-x)~a   dde
c^ed^~g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/X5HLThcIqvTLYqJAoITLDkTpVvioa2pqViRzVVQA6aQEe4UkDQ0NLs0K3QrNukQFBYWUlFSu5LjUlLi69P///@uWAwA)

After printing each `"DUCK\n"`, makes a binary choice for whether to go back to `"DUCK\n"`, or print `"GOOSE"` and terminate.

So, 1/2 of all runs will see one DUCK, 1/4 will see two, 1/8 will see three, and so on.

The left blob under the `Z`'s contains the encoding for `"DUCK\n"`, and the right blob under the `Z`'s contains `"GOOSE"`. The connecting bit between the two makes the random decision, and the rest is just infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 42 bytes

```
D,f,?:,@n
R9
y:duck
W,x:y,O,x:0,R9
x:goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ03H3krHIY8ryJKr0iqlNDmbK1ynwqpSxx9IGugARSus0vPzi1P//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby, 49 Bytes**

```
(rand(9)+1).times do
puts "duck"
end
puts "goose"
```

*Explanation*

1. Generate an integer between 0 and 9 and add 1 to it
2. Each of those times print a duck
3. End the loop and print goose

Comment: With `0.upto(rand 9){puts:duck};puts:goose` you can get rid of the extra parenthesis needed due to the +1.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>59</s> 55 bytes

```
END{for(srand();i++<9*rand();)print"duck";print"goose"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/f1c@lOi2/SKO4KDEvRUPTOlNb28ZSC8rRLCjKzCtRSilNzlayhrDT8/OLU5Vq//8HAA)

-4 bytes thanks to manatwork

Comment: No need for parenthesis around `print`'s argument.

Answer (score 1):

## RUST, 240 bytes

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::distributions::{IndependentSample, Range};
fn main() {
  let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
  println!("{}", std::iter::repeat("Duck\n").take(Range::new(1, 9).ind_sample(&mut rng)).collect::<String>()+"Goose");
}
```

You can try it here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release
Copy and Paste
Sorry I dont have shorten link due their server error!

Comment: Hi there -- I don't know RUST at all but there's definitely some unnecessary whitespace you can remove. If there's any way to make shorter variable names, that will also help.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=296aac35f6f5252ace3e26ab426b1488&version=stable 114 bytes

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fe7a4576a8c3c8b02dafd1ebecd88e36&version=stable 101 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [mIRC v.7.51](https://www.mirc.com), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

Also works in most older versions, and definitely in newer versions.

```
//echo $str(Duck $crlf,$r(1,9)) Goose
```

**How It Works?**

```
$r(1,9) -> Generates a random number between 1 and 9
$crlf -> Prints the carriage return and linefeed characters (ASCII 13 and 10 respectively)
$str -> Reoeats the first argument required number of times
echo -> Prints the succeeding text in the window
```

*-3 bytes -> Changed* `$rand` *to* `$r`

Please note that mIRC echo does not recognize the newline character, so the text is printed in the same line in the window. However, the text contains the newline character which means that if you copy paste it anywhere, then you will see the text in multiple lines. I believe this is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript - 61 bytes

```js
document.write('duck<br>'.repeat(Math.random()*10+1)+'goose')
```

[Live here](https://js.do/code/203230)

#### Second change - 57 bytes

```js
document.write('duck<br>'.repeat(new Date()%9+1)+'goose')
```

Thanks @Martin

Another way is using console.log, but it is not visual for people to see the answer

#### 52 bytes

```js
console.log('duck\n'.repeat(new Date()%9+1)+'goose')
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP11DPaU0OTsmT12vKLUgNbFEIy@1XMElsSRVQ1PVUttQU1s9PT@/OFVd8/9/AA)

#### 46 bytes with alert

```js
alert('duck\n'.repeat(new Date()%9+1)+'goose')
```

[Try it online](http://js.do/code/203230)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You don't need to print `duck` so many times, so you can save a byte by reducing `*10` to `*9` or something like that. And I think a common way to get a shorter indeterminate number would be `new Date()%9+1`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, I think about number 10 and 9 before but I forgot to try that number, and thanks for your suggestion about `new Date()%9+1` that helped me saved some bytes, I will update the code

Comment: The 52-byte version is completely fine. That's the usual output you'd use in a console (as opposed to a browser): https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP11DPaU0OTsmT12vKLUgNbFEIy@1XMElsSRVQ1PVUttQU1s9PT@/OFVd8/9/AA

Comment: I have added a better solution with "alert", It only 46 bytes.

Comment: save one byte by using `` with a literal newline instead of "" with \n

Comment: save another 4 bytes by using lambda: `_=>*duck
*.repeat(new Date()%9+1)+'goose'` (literal newline after duck and ` instead of *)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
VhOT"duck";"goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyzDP0QppTQ5W8laKT0/vzj1/38A)

Pretty simple. Loops between 1 and 11 times, printing `duck`, then prints `goose`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```
fn->String.duplicate("duck
",:rand.uniform 2)<>"goose"end
```

Returns a string either one or two ducks.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83JrMgs@u/pr1dQWlKsofE/LU/XLrikKDMvXS@ltCAnMzmxJFVDKaU0OZtLSceqKDEvRa80LzMtvyhXwUjTxk4pPT@/OFUpNS/lv6aehqbmfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 45 characters

```
while {rand()<.9} puts\ duck
puts duck\ngoose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/PCMzJ1WhuigxL0VD00bPslahoLSkOEYhpTQ5mwvEBLNi8tLz84tT//8HAA)

#### Tcl, 55 characters

```
puts [string repeat duck\n [expr int(rand()*9+1)]]goose
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ tclsh <<< 'puts [string repeat duck\n [expr int(rand()*9+1)]]goose'
duck
duck
goose
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oLSkWCG6uKQoMy9doSi1IDWxRCGlNDk7Jk8hOrWioEghM69EoygxL0VDU8tS21AzNjY9P7849f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/attache), 33 bytes

```
Print=>Random[1,9]&"duck"'"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/P6AoM6/E1i4oMS8lPzfaUMcyVk0ppTQ5W0ldKT0/vzhV6f9/AA)

### Explanation

`Print=>` prints each element of:

`Random[1,9]&"duck"`, which repeats `"duck"` a random number between `1` and `9` times, and

`"goose"`, which is appended to the end with `'`.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 76 bytes

```
	X =TIME() * 100
S	OUTPUT ='DUCK'
	X =GT(X) X - 1	:S(S)
	OUTPUT ='GOOSE'
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNCwTbE09dVQ1NBS8HQwIArmNM/NCQgNETBVt0l1NlbnQukwj1EI0JTIUJBV8GQ0ypYI1iTC6HK3d8/2FWdy9XP5f9/AA)

The `TIME` function counts the amount of time (in tenths of a second) elapsed since the program began, which does have a bit of randomness. Since it's so short, however, we have to scale by 100 or else the time will be nearly always zero. Then it outputs `DUCK` until `X<0`, decrementing `X` each iteration, before printing `GOOSE`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP <s>55</s> 53 Bytes (Thanks manatwork)

```
for($i=0;$i<time();$i++)echo 'duck<br>';echo 'goose';
```

Legibly

```
for($i=0;$i<time();$i++){
    echo 'duck<br>';
}
echo 'goose';
```

Now, I haven't tested this, because I don't want to melt my old computer, but it will output one duck for every second since January 1, 1970, 0000 hours. (Then a goose)

Comment: Checked the [documentation of `mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php#refsect1-function.mktime-notes)? The Notes contains a good golfing hint: `mktime()` without parameter is equivalent with `time()`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 51 bytes

```
(p=print)"Duck"whilemath.random()>.3p"Duck"p"Goose"
```

Funky is surprisingly bad at Duck Duck Goose.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678/1@jwLagKDOvRFPJpTQ5W6k8IzMnNTexJEOvKDEvJT9XQ9NOz7gAIleg5J6fX5yq9P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## Kotlin <s>71</s> 65 bytes

```
for(i in 1..(1..9).shuffled()[0])println("duck");println("goose")
```

Thanks Makotosan for the tip on how to replace the random to shave a few bytes.

Comment: You can save a byte by using 9 instead of 10.

Also, you can shave off a few more by changing your random function to this:  

   `(1..9).shuffled()[0]`

So that your for loop looks like : `for(i in 1..(1..9).shuffled()[0])`

This will only work as long as you use small values.  If you get into the millions, it will take up a lot of CPU and memory.

Answer (score 1):

### shell, 65 bytes

```
f(){ echo duck&&expr `date +%N` % 2 >/dev/null&&f||echo goose;};f
```

[ideone](https://www.ideone.com/F2vJku)

Comment: Too many 2 character list operators, when the single character `;` would be enough. Also discarding `expr`'s output would be shorter with an assignment than with redirection: `f(){ echo duck;x=\`expr \\`date +%N\\` % 2\`&&f;};f;echo goose`

Comment: @manatwork Thank you for your advice. Just have fun.

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl6/Rakudo](https://perl6.org/), <s>27</s> 26 chars

```
say ｢Duck
｣x now%9~'Goose'
```

Change `now%9` to `9.rand` for sub-second nondeterminism at a cost of 1 char.

Answer (score 1):

## golflua, 38 characters

```
M.rs(O.t())!@w"duck"!$M.r()<.1w"goose"
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ opt/eso/golflua-1.0/src/golflua -e 'M.rs(O.t())!@w"duck"!$M.r()<.1w"goose"'
duck
duck
goose
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 65 bytes

```
"  ^
1  \.701
0      .
0.117.99
0
1 "
"""v
  " 103.11:1:..5.101.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HckxCoBADATAPq9Y8oAli8hxV/kQEbRSEAsRwddHcdrZ5@U5t@NaMx2YTMDIErLAjxaUCmu1@NLN3W8DHIrum6ZG9lSIQ@YL)

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift 3/4](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <s>94</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
import Foundation;for _ in -1..<time(nil)%9{print("duck")};print("goose")
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/NDGB80022)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 40 bytes

```php
<?=str_pad(goose,5+5*date(m),"duck
",0);
```

prints one duck for every month (3 in March, 4 in April etc.)

Run with `-n` (no config file) or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17dbc6b37bd4b91d51d4a5536599131ea8143c1f).

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>50</s> 46 bytes

Giving a new language a try.

```lua
d="duck\n"print(d:rep(os.time()%9|1).."goose")
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/xVYppTQ5OyZPqaAoM69EI8WqKLVAI79YryQzN1VDU9WyxlBTT08pPT@/OFVJ8/9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

Too many ducks for one goose!

```c
main(){while(rand())puts("duck");puts("goose");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6PCMzJ1WjKDEvRUNTs6C0pFhDKaU0OVtJ0xrCSc/PL04F8mr//wcA)

Answer (score 1):

## WinDBG, 39 bytes

```
.foreach(_ {#}){.echo duck};.echo goose
```

How it works:

```
.foreach(_                              $$ Loop..., using an unused variable _
           {#})                         $$ ...through each space separated "word" of the next disassembly text
               {.echo duck};            $$ Print duck on each iteration
                            .echo goose $$ Print goose at the end
```

The dissambly text will be formatted something like this. The examples on MSDN don't have the first line, so maybe that only shows if you have symbols for the code that you're currently debugging. But definitely the `assembly_details` part can contain spaces (or be empty) which will cause a different number of ducks to print.

```
dll!Function [source @ line]:
address binary_code      assembly_mnemonic     assembly_details
```

With the above example, it would print (in parenthesis is the value of `_`, not actually printed)

```
duck (dll!Function)
duck ([source)
duck (@)
duck (line]:)
duck (address)
duck (binary_code)
duck (assembly_mnemonic)
duck (assembly_details)
goose
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/), 45 bytes

Twig is a templating language written in PHP.

This uses the `random()` function up to 9.
Then, it will loop all elements in the range of `1 - random(9)`.

This causes a bug: `random(<n>)` returns values up to the `<n>` value (including 0).
However, twig allows to make a range of `1 - 0`, creating an array with 2 elements.

This ensures that there is always, at least, 1 duck.

```
{%for _ in 1..random(9)%}duck
{%endfor%}goose
```

You can try it on https://twigfiddle.com/w0m6p6

Comment: I guess it´s a feature, not a bug. `0..random(9)` and `random(9)..0` should also work.

Comment: Well, it could cause a bug. And yes, those work as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [jamal](http://verhas.com/peter/progs/perl/jamal/), 47 characters

```
{@format time=ss}{#for i/0..{#time}/duck
}goose
```

(No proper random, no subdivision of seconds, so the most random thing is the second.)

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jamal.pl duck.jam
duck
duck
goose
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>84</s> 82 bytes

```
from random import*
a="Duck"
print a
while randint(0,9)%2:print a
print"Goose"
```

EDIT: changed random number function

Answer (score 1):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), 58 bytes

```
" v03.1:1:1:..5.01.@
" ^
1;v
.  100.11
0 7     7
1.101.99.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P9fSaHMwFjP0AoE9fRM9QwM9Ry4lBTiuAyty7j0FBQMDQz0DA25DBTMFUDAnMtQzxCoxtJS7/9/AA)

Shorter than the [previous Labyrinth solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158101/31203). This is the first Labyrinth program I have written with moving code!

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Basic For Applications, 37 bytes

```
do:?"duck":loop while rnd>.1:?"goose"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 45 bytes

```
"duck\n".repeat((1..9).shuffled()[0])+"goose"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcc9CgIxEEDhPqcYUs0gBC0VPIWlWgxuEsPGScjPNsuePebBV7w1tRhkuC7w4yC4ceHiYao3eLQSxBPsCmZ5TouCGYnUodTGEfJ9H3rpn/Ul2hSbLTfEizFXMvXbnYt2QXqe33TSPqVq9TjGHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 106 bytes

```java
a->{int r = new Random().nextInt(9);while(r>0){System.out.println("duck");r--;}System.out.print("goose");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY@xTsQwDIb3ewqrUzI0YkURtzOwcBILYnDbUNJLnShx7kBVn7243E1IHmz//u3PE16wjcnRNJw3P6eYGSbpmco@mFekIc720AcsBV7Q0@KJXf7E3kFXmSMtl@gHsYzqbU9Q2/UAUBjZ9/cR6AImX@AJNmyP@wbIUpC7wu2A0obcNz8Tq0dtr18@OJWPD3o5/RR2s4mVTcriC6SaofbnRtvctnb9r6tmjLE4kdfNCoZEql0QkjvQH@wsf6gTi2F8/0C93PDM/gPVEMS8br8)

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, <s>46</s> 40 bytes

```
d="duck\n";print(d^rand(UInt)*d*"goose")
```

Upon invocation, this will print out between 1 and 2^64 instances of "duck " on the screen before printing "goose". If your computer uses a 64-bit processor like most people do, this will almost certainly blow whatever process memory allowance there is and cause an OOM error which Julia catches and returns to you gracefully.

If you want to test it, put "UInt8" instead of "UInt" to pare it down to between 1 and 256 ducks before a goose.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 97 Bytes

```
a=>{var r=new Random();var s="";do{s+="Duck\n";}while(r.Next(9)>0);s+="Goose";Console.Write(s);};
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 21 bytes

```
"esooG"fSxXFa"kcuD"|H
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/Xym1OD/fXSktuCLCLVEpO7nURanG4/9/AA)

#### How it works

```
"esooG"fSxXFa"kcuD"|H

"esooG"                Push "Goose" in reverse order
       f               Push 15
        Sx             Push a random number in [0,1)
          X            Exponentiation
           F  ...  |   Pop n and repeat the content n times
            a"kcuD"    Push "Duck\n" in reverse order
                    H  Print the content of the stack as chars
                       from top to bottom, then halt
```

The result of `fSxX` is in the range `[1,15)`, but `F` takes the ceiling of the popped value as the repeat count, so the actual result has `[2,15]` ducks. (1 duck is theoretically possible, but the chance is about `2**-52`.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 567 bytes

```
Go to Heisenberg's: w 1 r, 3 r, 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to The Underground: s 1 r 1 l.[a]Switch to plan "b" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground."duck\n" is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Zoom Zoom: n 3 l 2 r.Go to Writer's Depot: w.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office: n 1 r 2 r 1 l.Go to The Underground: n 1 r 1 l.Switch to plan "a".[b]"duck\ngoose\n" is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot: n 3 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office: n 1 r 2 r 1 l.
```

Prints a very large number of ducks, almost always enough to overflow the output buffer on TIO, and then prints a goose, then terminates with an error. Note: "duck\ngoose\n" can't be shortened to just "goose\n", because Heisenberg's could return exactly zero (although the chance is miniscule).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBBS8QwEIX/yiOXvUhh11vPgt5cUBFc95C202zYOlOSlPrvY7JGWQuKgpc5TN57me8F/WpjvBYEwQ1ZT9yQMytfY8Ya7gKXeawxVFvbHqcRGqP2SWbIwYhlk533B8IDd8npZOKues9bbGv4HHkK2@n93WxDe8i6cdAM1SjYHiwQJliPWduQ4v/0r@qm9vjM6swPHfDobCC38riiUUK57knk5TRqcKIcsIErT1/1qYofj9iKD7jte9tS8Z9tcniG3hTwb5rhz2aWtWhV7Zp9ATMinn7Jt4T4gBz@DybG@AY)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 50 bytes

```
exec("print('duck');"*abs(id({})))
print("goose")
```

Could be shortened by 1 byte using

```
id(1)
```

But than there will be no random on the same environment.

#### Explanation

id() -- returns unique id of python object, usually adress in memory, because we getting ID of freshly created hash it will different every run.

Comment: This usually errors as the program runs out memory trying to store an extremely large string

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64 Machine Code (Linux), 40 bytes

```
0000000000000000 <goose>:
   0:   67 6f
   2:   6f
   3:   73 65
   5:   0a

0000000000000006 <duck>:
   6:   64 75 63
   9:   6b
   a:   0a

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <_start>:
   0:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
   2:   40 b7 01                mov    $0x1,%dil
   5:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
   a:   b2 06                   mov    $0x6,%dl
   c:   0f 05                   syscall
   e:   0f c7 f1                rdrand %ecx
  11:   67 e3 ec                jecxz  0 <_start>
  14:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
  16:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  1b:   0f 05                   syscall
```

The first 12 bytes are used to store the strings "goose\n" and "duck\n". Technically when duck is printed, it prints 6 bytes (while "duck\n" is 5 bytes), but chances are that the byte after where duck is located in the binary will be an invisible character.

The blocks that preceded the syscall are just setting up the sys_write system call. Normally in x86-64 this looks like (in Intel syntax rather than AT&T):

```
b8 01 00 00 00                   mov    $0x1,%eax ; syscall number for sys_write
bf 01 00 00 00                   mov    $0x1,%edi ; fd number for STDOUT
48 be 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    movabs $0x0,%rsi ; pointer to where the "duck\n" string is located (nasm syntax)   
ba 06 00 00 00                   mov    $0x6,%edx ; number of bytes to write
0f 05                            syscall
```

However we can use the lower bits addressing of the registers to produce shorter x86 opcodes.

For the second syscall, only rax gets clobbered (since it holds the return value for sys_write), so we have to reset it.

The randomness comes from using the `rdrand` instruction, which sets a hardware random number into ecx. The next instruction then jumps back to _start if ecx is 0. This means that "duck" will only be printed again with a chance of 1/(2^32). However small this chance is, it technically is possible and non-deterministic.

The more interesting way to print out a series of "duck" strings before "goose" is to replace the rdrand and jecxz instructions with:

```
66 0f c7 f3             rdrand %bx
66 85 db                test   %bx,%bx
75 e9                   jne    0 <_start>
```

Unfortunately this takes 2 more bytes, but the effect is that the result of rdrand is stored into bx, which is a 16 bit register. Additionally, each time this is run, the chance the code jumps back to *start* and prints "duck" again is (2^16 - 1)/(2^16). This means that after about 50000 loops there's over a 50% chance of bx being 0 in at least one of the loops. (The exact amount is 45426 loops). For a 90% chance of bx being 0 in at least one of the loops, just over 150000 loops need to occur.

Finally, with normal program behavior, this program should call sys_exit with this code:

```
0000000000000020 <_exit>:
  20:   b8 3c 00 00 00          mov    $0x3c,%eax
  25:   31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
  27:   0f 05                   syscall
```

But since we can just leave this out and the program will exit with a segmentation fault, this is fine. The challenge has already been completed by this point.

For better inline comments, check out the original nasm source code in [my repo](https://github.com/Davey-Hughes/ppcg/tree/master/duck_duck_goose).

Comment: Suggest `xor %esi, %esi` instead of `mov $0x0, %esi`

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 40 bytes

```apl
{⎕←'Duck'}⍣{1=?9}2⋄⎕←'Goose'
```

Sure there's already a shorter Dyalog solution, but it doesn't have the potential to print Duck an infinite amount of times :P

Also the 2 does absolutely nothing lol

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR39RHbRPUXUqTs9VrH/Uurja0tbesNXrU3QKVcc/PL05V//8fAA)

Comment: You say the 2 does nothing, but removing it gives you “goose” every time. If must do something?

Comment: @AJFaraday well ok it does do something. it forces the niladic dfn on the left to get called otherwise it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-R`, 15 bytes

```
`Ýõãµ&o `qÍtMq
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=YN314wO1Jm+gYHHNdE1x&input=LVI=)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84), 20 bytes

```
While not(rand:Disp "DUCK:End:Disp "GOOSE
```

Prints `DUCK` on a new line until `rand` returns `1`, where it will then print `GOOSE`.
This program will take a significant amount of time to complete due to [the specifications of `rand`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/rand).
If `rand`just so happens to have `196164532` as its seed, then the program won't print any `DUCK`s.  This can be fixed by adding **4 bytes**:

```
0:While not(Ans:Disp "DUCK:rand:End:Disp "GOOSE
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does *not* equal byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 139 bytes

OP wanted a full program, so here you go

```
interface I{static<T>void p(T t){System.out.println(t);}static void main(String[]a){for(p("duck");Math.random()>.1;p("duck"));p("goose");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcq9CsMgFEDhV5FMOlTobMneoVOylQwXNalJ/UFvAkV8dmtb6HbgfCsccFrVVqtxqOMMUpNrTgho5GXsD28UCXQkyPLwSqgt9zvyEJt@OopMlJ8lX2nBODpgu8t9ApZnH2mgndrl1jFxA3zwCE55S1nPz@K/2CcX75NurJRa3w)

Comment: [120 bytes](https://tio.run/##PcyxCsMgEIDhVxEnJVToLO3eoVPGtsOhJjVBr5wXoYQ8u8mU@f/4J6hwmfzcWswcaAAXxGMtDBydqBi9SBCz6pliHl8f0GsFEnSTfnHzO0s7ICn7BP4aguwxKX03V0vdKbTt/4VDMriw@R0bVtTJEbGEo21bazs) by creating a String to print at the end. EDIT: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcuxDoMgEADQXyFMEFO2TsTuHTo51g4XQIsGrjlOEmP8duzb3wIVbotfW4uZA03ggngehYGjExWjFwliVgNTzPP7A/qoQIJ66Te3jlnaCUnZF/DXEGSPSemHuVvqetJ22AuHZHBj8/t/VtTJGbEEqe15tnYB) by exponentially growing the amount of `"duck\n"`.

Comment: Then again, [an extension of my Java lambda](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157999/52210) is [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcixCsIwEADQXwk3JYjZXFRwdnDqqA5HEuu15K4k14KUfnt0cHxvwAX3QxxbI9ZUXhiSua5VUSmYRSiajMS200Lc35/o1u5TNWUvs/rpl2rtDfXtC3KUbN3ZHy4Q5zA@GI4AbvdHL1ITuNO2tfYF).. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Trigger](http://yiap.nfshost.com/esoteric/trigger/trigger.html), 52 bytes

```
ABddduuuccckkk


AAB	 	 	 	 	 	 	 	Bgggooo ooossseee
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTE9PLfr/39EpJSWltLQ0OTk5Ozubi4vL0dGJUwEFOqWnp@fn5ysAcXFxcWpq6v//AA)

Comment: I think you missed a line when copy-pasting.

Comment: @negativeseven I did not copy-paste. Also, there is no line missing\

Comment: Ah, TIO just wrapped the line but the UI here didn't. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 25 bytes

```
1 9rand+{"duck"n}*"goose"
```

#### Explanation

```
1 9rand+        # pick a random integer in [1, 10]
{"duck"n}       # push 'duck\n'
*               # repeat the previous code block the random number of times
"goose"         # push 'goose'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Roblox Studio - 71 bytes

> [@BenjaminUrquhart Better find more games to answer in](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157897/duck-duck-goose/178702#comment437784_178702)

Looks like I found another game (a reasonably popular one too)!

```
print('duck')
while math.random(9)>1 do print('duck')end
print('goose')
```

Apparently 0 is a truthy value in Roblox/Lua so I had to use `>1`.
You can seed this with `math.randomseed(tick())`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 22 bytes

```
"duck"akqf'RA*"goose"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/18ppTQ5WykxuzBNPchRSyk9P784Vcnh/38A)

#### Explanation

```
"duck"akq                Push the string "duck" with a newline on the end
         'RA             Random number 0-15
            *            Duplicate the string so that there are n copies python
                             style (bug? 0 still leaves one copy; I'm ok with this)
             "goose"     Concatenate "goose" onto the end
                    @    Print and terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 19 bytes

```
(~2%1+|duck\
)goose
```

Explanation

```
(~2%          Repeat random number in range 0,1
    1+        Increment to range 1,2
      |       Do:
       duck   Push "duck"
           \  and a newline
)             End
goose         Push "goose"
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y05N//9fo85I1VC7JqU0OTuGSzM9P7849f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `oH`, 12 bytes

```
℅(‛¦ø,)`go⋎Ǒ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJvSCIsIiIsIuKEhSjigJvCpsO4LClgZ2/ii47HkSIsIiIsIiJd)

The `H` flag (preset stack to 100) is really useful lol

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 47 <s>59</s> bytes

```fortran
print'(A)',('duck',j=0,mod(i,5)**2),'goose';end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/icn5uQopFmn5qVwFZcmFeWXlmTmpSqk/S8oyswrUddw1FTX0VBPKU3OVtfJsjXQyc1P0cjUMdXU0jLS1FFPz88vTlUHaf7/HwA)
  <s><sub>[59 bytes](https://tio.run/##PctNCoAgEEDhfadwp4ZB25AOo42KZU74c/6JCto9PngeSysmT8F/QZtJiXntMgy124K9xeyYJ0C2r7MytooTQUS1SKmvEnMbFYe@Hfx5AH8LiNW9SHQD)</sub></s>

Had to put this code into a subroutine otherwise the loop doesn't run. Some [weird compiler stuff going on](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24224396/148889), probably because `i` wasn't initialised, to produce randomness.

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22 bytes

```
"duck"a>x
ose"r>o<>"go
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiXCJkdWNrXCJhPnhcbm9zZVwicj5vPD5cImdvIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIiLCJzdGFjayI6IiIsInN0YWNrX2Zvcm1hdCI6Im51bWJlcnMiLCJpbnB1dF9mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyJ9)

Comment: That interpreter it's fascinating to watch!

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `TO`, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ɼ{`_*£}`⁾®
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0Uoi_UuyCpaUlaboW60_uqU6I1zq0uDbhUeO-Q-uWFCclF0PlFkBpAA)

Or, **12 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)** flagless:

```
Tɼ{`_*£}`⁾®£
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWm0JO7qlOiNc6tLg24VHjvkPrDi1eUpyUXAyVhikDAA)

##### Explanation

```python
Tɼ{`_*£}`⁾®£  # Full program
T             # Push 10. The T flag implicitly does this.
 ɼ            # Pop it and push a random number from 1 to 10.
  {    }      # Loop that many times:
   `_*        #  Push the compressed string "Duck"
      £       #  And print it with a newline
        `⁾®   # Push the compressed string "Goose"
           £  # And print it. The O flag forces the implicit output.
```