# Blue duck, red duck, gray duck

Tags: code-golf

So, last week I posted a challenge to play [Duck, Duck, Goose](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157897/duck-duck-goose). This lead to a number of Minnesotans commenting about their regional ['Gray duck' variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck,_duck,_goose#Duck,_Duck,_Gray_Duck).

So here's the rules:

Using this list of colours:

```
Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Indigo
Violet
Gray
```

Write a program to follow these rules:

1. Select one of these colours, and prepend it to the word 'duck' and print the result to a new line.
2. If the colour was not 'Gray', repeat step 1.
3. If the colour was 'Gray', end your program.

Rules which must be followed:

- The program should not consistently print the same number of lines.
- It can begin on 'Gray duck', but should not do consistently.
- There should be exactly one duck on each line and no empty lines are output.
- There should be at least one space between a colour and a duck.
- White space before and after the significant output does not matter.
- The case of the output doesn't matter.
- Colours can be repeated.
- The output doesn't have to contain every colour every time, but it must be possible that your code will output every colour.
- No colours outside the above array can be included.
- Either grey or gray are acceptable in your answer.
- Colours should not consistently be in the same order.
- Aim for the shortest program. Smallest number of bytes wins.

Example output:

```
Green duck
Orange duck
Yellow duck
Indigo duck
Yellow duck 
Gray duck
```

Thanks to @Mike Hill for first alerting me to this variation.

Comment: Any rules on the distribution on outcomes? Because I could generate valid outputs by picking from non-grey colours a random number of times, followed by printing `Grey` once (so I wouldn't have to pick from all of them and check whether I've picked `Grey`).

Comment: @MartinEnder That's fine. "Colours should not consistently be in the same order." matters, but there's nothing to stop you picking grey separately at the end.

Comment: Is the alternative spelling "gray" allowed?

Comment: @12Me21 Curious, tho. Is there a technical reason for that? Or just an aesthetic one?

Comment: Mostly just aesthetic, though it might affect golfing languages with built in string compression.

Comment: I believe "gray" should be allowed, even encouraged, because that's how [Minnesotans](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157897/duck-duck-goose#comment385289_157897) are [more likely to spell it](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5391/246891). ;)

Comment: @DLosc I almost feel like I should change the question now...

Comment: In my not-so-humble opinion, you are missing one extremely important duck color.  Blue is close, but not precise enough.

Comment: @cobaltduck We've got blue, we've got green. You can just mix up a batch ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(’Red ṆỴ »Ẹ Ɓ# Ñɦ ƲỤ ṡʂ Ɓ~’OɼD‘ _*‘+£`Ɓ~Q
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWN101HjXMDEpNUXi4s-3h7i0Kh3Y_3LVD4VijssLhiSeXKRzb9HD3EqDcwlNNQME6oFr_k3tcHjXMUIjXApLahxYnAIUDlxQnJRdDjYQZDQA)

##### Explanation

```python
(                     # While loop
 ’...’                # (condition)  Push compressed string of colours
      O               #              Split it on spaces
       ɼ              #              Pick a random item from this list
        D             #              Duplicate the item
         ‘ _*‘+       #              Append compressed string " duck"
               £      #              Pop and print with a newline
                `Ɓ~   #              Push compressed string "Grey"
                   Q  #              Check for inequality
                      # (body)  Do nothing
```

Answer (score 51):

### LuaLaTeX, <strike>220</strike> 211 characters

command:

```
lualatex -interaction nonstopmode
```

Not the shortest, but the fanciest. Based on [@skillmon's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159706/79196)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{tikzducks}\newcount\b\let~\def~\0{red}~\1{orange}~\2{yellow}~\3{green}~\4{blue}~\5{cyan}~\6{violet}~\7{gray}\loop\b\uniformdeviate8\tikz\duck[body=\csname\the\b\endcsname]; \ifnum\b<7\repeat\stop
```

Comment: Good heavens! This is just the best thing! You've made my day, Alex.

Comment: @AJFaraday indeed amazing idea to use `tikzducks` there :)

Comment: +1 and my apologies for choosing such a long package name!

Comment: @sam, you get my absolution

Comment: Hello mr. person who I definitely don't know from other technical communities like [TeX.sx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). Since this answer covers some birds in the family *Anatidae*, I feel compelled to provide a token of approval by upvoting it. `:)`

Answer (score 27):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 124 bytes

```
00 C0 AD 12 D0 85 02 A2 17 8E 18 D0 A5 02 F0 03 0A 90 02 49 1D 85 02 A8 CA 10
02 A2 2F BD 42 C0 D0 F6 88 D0 F3 86 FB E8 BD 42 C0 F0 06 20 16 E7 E8 D0 F5 AA
BD 73 C0 F0 06 20 16 E7 E8 D0 F5 A6 FB D0 C9 60 00 C7 52 45 59 00 D2 45 44 00
CF 52 41 4E 47 45 00 D9 45 4C 4C 4F 57 00 C7 52 45 45 4E 00 C2 4C 55 45 00 C9
4E 44 49 47 4F 00 D6 49 4F 4C 45 54 00 20 44 55 43 4B 0D 00
```

**[Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B%22controlPort2%22:%22joystick%22,%22primaryControlPort%22:2,%22keys%22:%7B%22SPACE%22:%22%22,%22RETURN%22:%22%22,%22F1%22:%22%22,%22F3%22:%22%22,%22F5%22:%22%22,%22F7%22:%22%22%7D,%22files%22:%7B%22duck.prg%22:%22data:;base64,AMCtEtCFAqIXjhjQpQLwAwqQAkkdhQKoyhACoi+9QsDQ9ojQ84b76L1CwPAGIBbn6ND1qr1zwPAGIBbn6ND1pvvQyWAAx1JFWQDSRUQAz1JBTkdFANlFTExPVwDHUkVFTgDCTFVFAMlORElHTwDWSU9MRVQAIERVQ0sNAA==%22%7D,%22vice%22:%7B%22-autostart%22:%22duck.prg%22%7D%7D)** -- Usage: `SYS49152`.

[image: screenshot]

---

#### Explanation (commented disassembly):

```
         00 C0       .WORD $C000        ; load address
.C:c000  AD 12 D0    LDA $D012          ; current rasterline as seed
.C:c003  85 02       STA $02            ; to "random" value
.C:c005  A2 17       LDX #$17           ; cfg for upper/lower, also use as
.C:c007  8E 18 D0    STX $D018          ;    initial index into colors array
.C:c00a   .loop:
.C:c00a  A5 02       LDA $02            ; load current random val
.C:c00c  F0 03       BEQ .doEor         ; zero -> feedback
.C:c00e  0A          ASL A              ; shift left
.C:c00f  90 02       BCC .noEor         ; bit was shifted out -> no feedback
.C:c011   .doEor:
.C:c011  49 1D       EOR #$1D
.C:c013   .noEor:
.C:c013  85 02       STA $02            ; store new random val
.C:c015  A8          TAY                ; use as counter for next color string
.C:c016   .findloop:
.C:c016  CA          DEX                ; next char pos in colors (backwards)
.C:c017  10 02       BPL .xok           ; if negative ...
.C:c019  A2 2F       LDX #$2F           ;    load length of colors - 1
.C:c01b   .xok:
.C:c01b  BD 42 C0    LDA .colors,X      ; load character from colors
.C:c01e  D0 F6       BNE .findloop      ; not zero, try next character
.C:c020  88          DEY                ; decrement random counter
.C:c021  D0 F3       BNE .findloop      ; not zero, continue searching
.C:c023  86 FB       STX $FB            ; save character position
.C:c025  E8          INX                ; increment to start of color
.C:c026   .outloop:
.C:c026  BD 42 C0    LDA .colors,X      ; output loop for color string
.C:c029  F0 06       BEQ .duckout
.C:c02b  20 16 E7    JSR $E716
.C:c02e  E8          INX
.C:c02f  D0 F5       BNE .outloop
.C:c031   .duckout:
.C:c031  AA          TAX                ; A is now 0, use as char pos for duck
.C:c032   .duckoutloop:
.C:c032  BD 73 C0    LDA .duck,X        ; output loop for duck string
.C:c035  F0 06       BEQ .outdone
.C:c037  20 16 E7    JSR $E716
.C:c03a  E8          INX
.C:c03b  D0 F5       BNE .duckoutloop
.C:c03d   .outdone:
.C:c03d  A6 FB       LDX $FB            ; load saved character position
.C:c03f  D0 C9       BNE .loop          ; not zero -> continue main loop
.C:c041  60          RTS                ; zero was start of "Grey" -> done
.C:c042   .colors:
.C:c042  00 c7 52 45    .BYTE 0, "Gre"
.C:c046  59 00 d2 45    .BYTE "y", 0, "Re"
.C:c04a  44 00 cf 52    .BYTE "d", 0, "Or"
.C:c04e  41 4e 47 45    .BYTE "ange"
.C:c052  00 d9 45 4c    .BYTE 0, "Yel"
.C:c056  4c 4f 57 00    .BYTE "low", 0
.C:c05a  c7 52 45 45    .BYTE "Gree"
.C:c05e  4e 00 c2 4c    .BYTE "n", 0, "Bl"
.C:c062  55 45 00 c9    .BYTE "ue", 0, "I"
.C:c066  4e 44 49 47    .BYTE "ndig"
.C:c06a  4f 00 d6 49    .BYTE "o", 0, "Vi"
.C:c06e  4f 4c 45 54    .BYTE "olet"
.C:c072  00             .BYTE 0
.C:c073   .duck:
.C:c073  20 44 55 43    .BYTE " duc"
.C:c077  4b 0d 00       .BYTE "k", $d, 0
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your demo doesn't seem to output any duck-related content.

Comment: @AJFaraday please notice the "usage" part ... the command to run it is `sys 49152`.

Comment: Okay, that made my day :)

Comment: haha good :D just in case anyone cares, you have to type the `sys` command because it's a plain machine code program, and the normal `run` on the C64 only runs BASIC programs. Of course it's simple to link a "BASIC header", I don't do it here to save bytes ;)

Comment: That was awesome.  It's been a while since I've written c64 assembly.

Comment: @lsd: same here! my very first program was 6502 assembly on a C64,because I just got it and a friend gave me the 6502 book with a task "write a game!" to jumsptart me into writing something! (great way! it was a great motivator to not just read, but actually write something). wrote a 192 bytes (iirc) "Snake" program (with a, imo, clever double index pointing to the head & to the tail of the snake's position)... first try: it zoomed past the bottom edge, 'eating' into the rest of the ram, growing on any "@", as I forgot to set up the walls ^^

Answer (score 12):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 79 bytes

```perl
say$_=(Grey,Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet)[rand 8]." duck"until/y/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIl3lbDvSi1UicoNUXHvygxLz1VJzI1Jye/XAconJqn45RTmqrjmZeSmZ6vE5aZn5NaohkNVJaiYBGrp6SQUpqcrVSaV5KZo1@p////v/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBgA)

Answer (score 11):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 1995 bytes

```
Go to Heisenberg's:w 1 r 3 r 1 l.[a]Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.8 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.8 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:n 1 l 3 l 1 l 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.Go to Divide and Conquer:w 1 r 3 r 1 r 2 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:e 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Trunkers:w 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.Go to What's The Difference:w 2 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:e 1 r 1 l 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Multiplication Station:w 1 r 2 r 1 r 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Addition Alley:n 2 l 1 r 3 l 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.'Red duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Orange duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Yellow duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Green duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Blue duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Indigo duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Violet duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.'Grey duck' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l 1 l.[b]Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.Go to Narrow Path Park:n 3 r 1 l 1 r.Go to The Underground:e 1 r.Switch to plan "c" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to Writer's Depot:s 2 r 1 l 2 l.Switch to plan "b".[c]Go to Narrow Path Park:n 4 l.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:e 1 r 4 r 1 l.Go to Writer's Depot:s 1 r 1 l 2 l.Switch to plan "a" if no one is waiting.[d]Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 2 r.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l.Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.Switch to plan "d".[e]Go to Heisenberg's:n 3 r 3 r.Switch to plan "a".
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVXBbtswDP0VIhffDCTpocita4Fuh7VB063YshwUi7EJq5JHy8vy9Zlsy0XiOo6bHWwh1DP5yEcyVvyl/f7egDXwGSlHvUaOg3y2hTEwTN0zBhUuxWpOUVpkICATuYPFyBAb0nH55R39IYkgtIRbo38XyOE1UA5bQbaECAsLKzhKSEl4KF6RjTLxbhioJtd1NdMlOUdSNWf4QZZ98K@FspQpioQlo0sC5enpvPd1VDGGSX32RrjdRcpo9C79rxlWyZTP5ExCL4mwQQ7PCTo@mw0y6gh7v3jmQqfIuQ/505jX6jVr8moALpvpRdFrN513zufE99MFdR//Z69gJcuQPrmRkqrQN0ph47OblRfdiw1Xl3g@NrqenlTyc9PX/YK6Cn/T0s0sm0LLMHhCCbKI0l86aBXshckiO1XuMDM2DB5ZOF8DwT9QKbMdCL5nRD0Q@0kVQzl80ZJiMxD8nYxCO5zwroKeAfrmPjL6JVRtyXXvlnwQzK6Gc2ET9@LUu2ubnUO/dqsF4ufyWOe6m8PFlmyUlPeZEhpG0QhoA9qA2yMHmXyogzpzzJvJrXZSO@x6FC6j1clszk3F3OQWHjcbelsfBxY/t1d@cZxgN@5hJ04UZSl71VoUWu9gkRLmh2q1zdW8ck9nvOODJ/i0cdJVFVcdf811f0w79BejcL//Bw)

I think it's worth noting that 47% of this code is just picking a random integer from 1 to 8.
Also, Taxi is so verbose that it is way shorter to hard code the `duck\n` after each color rather than concatenating it later.
Here's the un-golfed version:

```
Go to Heisenberg's: west 1st right 3rd right 1st left.

[Pick up a random INT 1-8 going to The Underground]
[a]
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
8 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
8 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: north 1st left 3rd left 1st left 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
Go to Divide and Conquer: west 1st right 3rd right 1st right 2nd right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Go to Cyclone: east 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.
Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Trunkers: west 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to What's The Difference.
Go to What's The Difference: west 2nd right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Multiplication Station.
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: east 1st right 1st left 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Multiplication Station: west 1st right 2nd right 1st right 4th left.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Addition Alley: north 2nd left 1st right 3rd left 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.

[Use the random INT to select a color]
'Red duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Orange duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Yellow duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Green duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Blue duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Indigo duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Violet duck\n' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
'Grey duck' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left 1st left.
[b]
Pickup a passenger going to Narrow Path Park.
Go to Narrow Path Park: north 3rd right 1st left 1st right.
Go to The Underground: east 1st right.
Switch to plan "c" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.
Go to Writer's Depot: south 2nd right 1st left 2nd left.
Switch to plan "b".

[Output the selected color]
[c]
Go to Narrow Path Park: north 4th left.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: east 1st right 4th right 1st left.

[If the color was grey, exit by error]
Go to Writer's Depot: south 1st right 1st left 2nd left.
Switch to plan "a" if no one is waiting.

[Get rid of the rest of the colors]
[You could throw them off a bridge but you won't get paid]
[d]
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 2nd right.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left.
Switch to plan "e" if no one is waiting.
Switch to plan "d".

[Start over from the beginning]
[e]
Go to Heisenberg's: north 3rd right 3rd right.
Switch to plan "a".
```

Comment: That was fun to read.

Comment: Golly, that's esoteric! I can't begin to understand how it works. Lots of fun, tho :)

Comment: This seems related to [Fetlang](https://github.com/fetlang/fetlang)

Answer (score 9):

## [Java (OpenJDK 9)](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/), 133 bytes

```java
v->{for(int x=9;x>0;)System.out.println("Grey,Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet".split(",")[x+=Math.random()*8-x]+" duck");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY69asMwFIV3P8XFk5XIomODaw/tUDqEQgOBEjKosuzIkSUhXbkOwc/uqpkOfOeHM/CJl9ZJM7TX3apGZz3CkCCLqDTrohGorGGbKhOahwB7rgzcMwAXf7QSEJBjksmqFsbkFQf0yvSnM3DfB/KIArxZE@Io/csx5RrooF6nsrl31hfKIMz1rpqbp4ocbgHlyGxE5tIMalPk717e6Jds6afnppf0W2ptf2nC0tBXHSX9MK3qLT0qqyXmLDitsMhpTk7ztt5zvLDUbO1YkM1zOZ@3ObRRXHNSLWv1uNcxLoR0WJioNflnS7asfw)

### Explanations

```java
v->{                              // Void-accepting void lambda function
  for(int x=9;x>0;)               //  Loop until x is zero
    System.out.println(           //   Print...
        "Grey,Red,Orange,         //       colors, "Grey" first
         Yellow,Green,Blue,       //          more colors
         Indigo,Violet"           //          more colors
        .split(",")               //       as an array
          [x+=Math.random()*8-x]  //       pick one randomly, use implicit double to int cast with "x+=<double>-x" trick
        +" duck");                //      Oh, and append " duck" to the color.
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>93 91 90 89 87 86</s> 85 bytes

<sup>Thanks to [Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings) for saving 2 bytes, [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l) 1 byte and [Asone Tuhid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/77598/asone-tuhid) 1 byte!</sup>

```ruby
puts %w(Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Grey)[$.=rand(8)]+" duck"while$.<7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBtVwjKDVFwb8oMS89VSEyNScnv1zBvSg1NU/BKac0VcEzLyUzPV8hLDM/J7UEJFGpGa2iZwtUnqJhoRmrraSQUpqcrVSekZmTqqJnY/7/PwA)

Comment: You can remove `()` around the code and if you use `$.` instead of `s` to store the index, you can avoid creating `s` altogether (since `$.` is pre-initialised to the line number!) You'll need to move `Grey` to the end of the list and check for `$.<7` instead though. Hope that helps!

Comment: @DomHastings Thanks! I was looking for a way to get rid of `s=1` and `$.` was perfect!

Comment: I think you can also remove space after while, Ruby doesn't  seem to complain about that.

Comment: @KirillL. That's right, thanks! I previously had `while s...` and the space was needed. Didn't see this opportunity after changing `s` to `$.`.

Comment: [`Color+" duck"` saves 1 byte](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFhBtVwjKDVFwb8oMS89VSEyNScnv1zBvSg1NU/BKac0VcEzLyUzPV8hLDM/J7UEJFGpGa2iZwtUnqJhoRmrraSQUpqcrVSekZmTqqJnY/7/PwA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Cool, thanks! :)

Comment: @GolfWolf, you can also use p instead of puts, saves another 3 bytes :)

Comment: @Kapenaar I don't know if it is acceptable to output every line in quotes.

Answer (score 8):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 133 bytes

```fortran
f={s="";v=s;while{v!="grey"}do{v=["Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet","Grey"]select random 7;s=s+v+" duck\n"};s}
```

**Call with:**

```fortran
hint call f
```

**Example output:**

[image]

At first I somehow misread the challenge as if the goal was to just output a varying amount of lines, not necessarily ending at the "Grey duck" -line. Following that incorrect interpretation produced a slightly more interesting piece of code:

```fortran
f={s="";c=[1];c set[random 9,0];{s=s+(["Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet","Grey"]select random 7)+" duck\n"}count c;s}
```

Answer (score 7):

## pdfTeX, <strike>231</strike> <strike>220</strike> <strike>219</strike> <strike>209</strike> 207 bytes

```latex
\newcount\b\let~\def~\0{Red}~\1{Orange}~\2{Yellow}~\3{Green}~\4{Blue}~\5{Indigo}~\6{Violet}~\7{Gray}~\9{ }\newlinechar`z\loop\b\pdfuniformdeviate8\message{z\csname\the\b\endcsname\9duck}\ifnum\b<7\repeat\bye
```

## LuaTeX, <strike>216</strike> <s>206</s> 204 bytes

```latex
\newcount\b\let~\def~\0{Red}~\1{Orange}~\2{Yellow}~\3{Green}~\4{Blue}~\5{Indigo}~\6{Violet}~\7{Gray}~\9{ }\newlinechar`z\loop\b\uniformdeviate8\message{z\csname\the\b\endcsname\9duck}\ifnum\b<7\repeat\bye
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Erik the Outgolfer*

```
[“ëßigo°¯†¾›ÈŠÛˆ¨‡—°Íolet“#7ÝΩ©è'Ðœðý,®#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVMArP8wNWFiMWX//1vigJzDq8OfaWdvwrDCr@KAoMK@4oC6w4jFoMOby4bCqOKAoeKAlMKww41vbGV04oCcIzfDnc6pwqnDqCfDkMWTw7DDvSzCriP//w)

Comment: I've noticed a lot of these unreadable golfing languages. Is there a compiler from some more human-readable form?

Comment: @AJFaraday: Not that I'm aware of. The only golfing language I know which has one of those is Charcoal.

Comment: You can compress your string further, `ind` is `ëß`!

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer: Thanks! I checked all the way down to `indi`, but I assumed `ind` wasn't a word. Serves me right :P

Comment: @Emigna I actually had another 41-byte version, but then looked at yours and realized there was a miscompression there :P `[“†¾›ÈŠÛˆ¨‡—ëßigo°Íolet°¯“#ΩD’ Ðœ’«,'°¯Q#`

Comment: Gs2 has one also. But that language is not used so much these days.

Comment: Which ANSI code page have you used to write this program? Because written on Unicode, with multi-byte code points, it takes more than 40 bytes.

Comment: @Simón: The [05AB1E code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 68 bytes

```
"Grey","
Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Indigo
Violet"ṇṛS," duck"ẉS¬?↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X8m9KLVSSUeJKyg1hcu/KDEvPZUrMjUnJ7@cCyiTmsfllFOayuWZl5KZns8Vlpmfk1qi9HBn@8Ods4N1lBRSSpOzlR7u6gw@tMb@UduG//8B)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>84</s> 81 bytes

Thanks to Dom Hastings for -3 bytes.

```ruby
puts$_=%w[Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Grey].sample+" duck"until/y/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6C0pFgl3la1PDooNUXBvygxLz1VITI1Jye/XMG9KDU1T8EppzRVwTMvJTM9XyEsMz8ntQQkURmrV5yYW5CTqq2kkFKanK1UmleSmaNfqf//PwA)

Comment: If you store in `$_`, you can just have `until/y/` at the end for -3!

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 72

```bash
shuf -e {Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Grey}\ Duck|sed /y/q
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzijNE1BN1WhOig1Rce/KDEvPVUnMjUnJ79cx70oNTVPxymnNFXHMy8lMz1fJywzPye1BCRRWRuj4FKanF1TnJqioF@pX/j/PwA).

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 89 bytes

```php
do echo[Grey,Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet][$i=rand()%8]," Duck
";while($i);
```

Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d46be81de712f91a00fdaf2eb781d265af8bf13b).

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 107 bytes

```
x<>" duck"a>
x<^"deR"
x<^"egnarO"
x<^"wolleY"
x<^"neerG"
x<^"eulB"
x<^"ogidnI"
x<^"teloiV"
x"Grey duck"r>o|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v8LGTkkhpTQ5WynRjqvCJk4pJTVICcxITc9LLPKHsMvzc3JSIyHsvNTUIneoktIcJwgrPz0zJc8Twi5JzcnPDAOyldyLUishhhfZ5df8/w8A)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 104 bytes

```
f=_=>`grey,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet`.split`,`[n=Math.random()*8|0]+` duck
${n?f():``}`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##DctBCsIwEADAu6/w4CHRtXgUofoCXyDixmYbY@NuSdJKUd8eex2YpxlNaqLv85bFUmmEkwSqgjilSlvf6iO6SBNEsiDRsCOYKAR5w8zEcA8DgWfrncDo55qxSn3wGQEvXJ9NflRzs/JSer3/7q4bXNqh6RarD59apQ@IPyxaaV3@)

Comment: FWIW, I had [this variant](https://tio.run/##DcuxCsIwEADQ3a/QxST27KoIreAiDiI4CCJCQnOt0XhXmlTx62PWB@9pPiY0g@vjkthiSm1FVU1bITZiP@APzmjhNBjqEK7oPX8hMxLs/IhwIOs6hotjj1GUofcuatA3qo4mPsrcLL@lWqznq3uhp3ZsXhNdtHJGKjVMIbfScydbqVT6Aw), but I'm stuck at 104 bytes as well.

Comment: Shame we can't use `new Date` for the RNG here.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, <strike>130</strike>, <strike>128</strike>, <strike>127</strike>, <strike>126</strike>, 125 bytes

```python
from random import*
d,c=1,'Grey Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet'.split()
while d!=c[0]:d=choice(c);print(d,'duck')
```

-1 by @ElPedro!
-1 by me
-1 by @Bubbler!

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/WeakParallelDivisor)

Comment: Can you move Grey to the front and have `d!=c[0]` to save a byte?

Comment: `print(d,'duck')` to save a byte. The default delimiter is a space.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>138</s> <s>133</s> <s>120</s> <s>117</s> 116 bytes

```python
import os
while id:id=ord(os.urandom(1))%8;print"Grey Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet".split()[id],'duck'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcmxCsIwEADQ3a84CtIEpKCTKC4u4iQ4CCIO4h3t4TUXLgmlXx@7vhfnPGjY1cpjVMugaTUNLASMB8aTGjpNXbFPQB3d1vv1/hiNQ24uRjPcCeG2ZE/wJBGdYGEKcJZCcA3IvcKDVSg3XYrC2fkX43vTYvn@2lr/)

Much better with some ideas from @EriktheOutgolfer. Thanks!

-3 more with thanks to @ovs

-1 with thanks to @Rod for a cool new trick learned :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```matlab
do disp([strsplit('Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet'){i=randi(7)},' duck'])until i>6
disp('Grey duck')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYy9CgIxDIB3nyJbWnDWSQcXcRIcBBGH4xKOYGiONvU4xGevh87fj/Xevbg1MiApY7gXz2VU8YAXJjjnLg0MN1a1CY6ZOcFBK8MpkQwGVzFlx/iW3WKShG38rBGo9k98xJpcFGS/Wf3euPTzn8XWvg)

There are a bunch of different options that are all between 112 and 118 bytes... Some initialize an index in the start and decrements it by a random number for each loop, and waits until it's **0**. Others use `printf` instead of `disp` to avoid some brackets and so on.

Comment: Little question: Is there a symbol in octave that does the same as & in Excel, because I think it is possible to shorten the code even further then.

Comment: Unfortunately, no... Strings must be concatenated inside square brackets (or using functions such as `cat` and `horzcat`. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](http://php.net/), <s>133</s> <s>125</s> <s>111</s> <s>108</s> <s>97</s> 92 bytes

```
<?for(;$b=[Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet][rand(0,7)];)echo"$b duck
"?>Grey duck
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj4tv0jDWiXJNjooNUXHvygxLz1VJzI1Jye/XMe9KDU1T8cppzRVxzMvJTM9XycsMz8ntSQ2GqgsRcNAx1wz1lozNTkjX0klSSGlNDmbS8neDqirEsz5//9ffkFJZn5e8X/dFIXijPyikvj8gtS8@JLEdNv8PAA)

-8 bytes thanks to [@Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire)

-3 bytes thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

-11 bytes thanks to [@Dom Hastings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9365/dom-hastings)

Comment: In the color string and the test, change `Grey` to `X`, since it's not used. You'll gain 6 bytes.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oh true. Thanks for that :)

Comment: Reverse the `for`'s condition to need no parenthesis: `x!=$b=$a[array_rand($a)]`. BTW, `?>` terminates a statement, no need for `;` in front of it.

Comment: @manatwork Ohh, nice! I'll update my answer now!

Comment: You can save a few more bytes by not including `x` at all and using `$b=$a..` as the condition and using `rand(0,7)` instead of `array_rand`. You can remove the newline between `?>` and `Grey duck` too. Also your TIO link still had full tags, you can add `-d short_open_tag=on` to flags to get that working! :)

Comment: Thanks @DomHastings! I've updated my answer. Using `rand` instead of `array_rand` was a neat trick I hadn't thought of! I also didn't know about `-d short_open_tag=on` for tio :)

Answer (score 4):

### bash, 96 bytes

```
a=(Grey Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet);for((i=1;i;));{ echo ${a[i=RANDOM%8]} duck;}
```

Thanks to @DigitalTrauma.

Comment: Lots of opportunities to golf this - check out the [bash golfing tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash)

Comment: @DigitalTrauma I was in hurry, but I wanted a pure Bash solution w/no GNU coreutils. I could shrink it from 112 to 105 bytes.

Comment: Yep, I like the pure-bash answers too.  [Here's another 10 bytes off](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P9FWw70otVIhKDVFwb8oMS89VSEyNScnv1wBKJyap@CUU5qq4JmXkpmerxCWmZ@TWqLJlZZfpKGRaWtonWmtqVnNlZqcka@gUp0YnWkb5Ojn4u@rahFbq5BSmpzNVfv/PwA)

Comment: I stripped `>0`, however, I left `${#a}` instead of `8`.

Comment: Why do you need to keep `${#a}` instead of `8`?  This is code-golf - there is no need to give your code generalisability to be modified for a different number of colours.  All you need to do is meet the spec in the smallest number of bytes.

Comment: Clever, I like the use of a loop that exits when the index variable (which is not being used as an actual index lol) hits 1

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

*Thanks to Leo for saving 1 byte.*

```
.^/y/{K`Red¶Orange¶Yellow¶Green¶Blue¶Indigo¶Violet¶Grey
" duck¶">?G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/Xy9Ov1K/2jshKDXl0Db/osS89NRD2yJTc3Lyyw9tcy9KTc07tM0ppxQo6JmXkpmef2hbWGZ@TmoJWLKSS0khpTQ5@9A2JTt794T//wE)

#### Explanation

```
./y/^{K`Red¶Orange¶Yellow¶Green¶Blue¶Indigo¶Violet¶Grey
```

`.` suppresses implicit output at the end of the program (otherwise, we'd get two grey ducks). `/y/^{` wraps the entire program in a loop which continues as long as the working string doesn't contain a `y`. The rest of that line sets the working string to a linefeed-separated list of all the colours.

```
" duck¶">G?`
```

We grep a random line from the working string (and therefore a random colour). And we print the result with a trailing  `duck` and a linefeed.

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 114 bytes

```
{srand();for(split("Red9Orange9Yellow9Green9Blue9Indigo9Violet9Grey",A,9);r<8;print A[r]" duck")r=int(8*rand()+1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/urgoMS9FQ9M6Lb9Io7ggJ7NEQykoNcXSHyicnmoZmZqTk19u6V6Umppn6ZRTmmrpmZeSmZ5vGZaZn5NaApKoVNJx1LHUtC6ysbAuKMrMK1FwjC6KVVJIKU3OVtIssgWKaFhoQWzRNtSs/f@fCwA)

**Explanation**

```
{srand();                  # Seed rand to obtain different sequence each run
for(
     split("Red9Orange9Yellow9Green9Blue9Indigo9Violet9Grey",
            A,9);          # Split on 9 to avoid using '"'s
     r<8;
     print A[r]" duck")    # Print the colored ducks
     r=int(8*rand()+1)     # AWK uses 1-indexing not 0-indexing when splitting strings into arrays
}
```

Note that this requires "some" input. The input can be empty. To avoid the need for input prepend the first line with `BEGIN`

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 94 bytes

```powershell
for(;$r-ne'Grey'){$r=-split"Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Indigo
Violet
Grey"|Random;"$r Duck"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SMNapUg3L1XdvSi1Ul2zWqXIVre4ICezRCkoNYXLvygxLz2VKxKoOL@cC6gkNY/LKac0lcszLyUzPZ8rLDM/J7UEJFGpVBOUmJeSn2utpFKk4FKanK1U@/8/AA)

Loops until `$r` is equal to `Grey`. Inside the loop, `-split`s the literal string on newlines, chooses a `Random` one thereof, then prints out the color plus `Duck` (technically, it's left on the pipeline and pipeline cleanup on the next loop iteration causes a `Write-Output` to happen). Note that it's theoretically possible for `Grey` to never be chosen, and the loop to continue infinitely, but this almost never (in the probability sense) will happen.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 101 bytes

```r
cat(paste(c(sample(scan(,""),rexp(1),T),"gray"),"duck\n"))
Red
Orange
Yellow
Green
Blue
Indigo
Violet
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcixCgIxDADQPZ@RKYUu/oKL3CSICIJLaEM5jGlJe9z59dU3Pp8z8aDGfQgl6vxpKtQTG0XEEF2ORqcQ7yFicf7@C/OW3i/DEOAmGa7OVgSeolp3uLiIwVk3gcXyWio81qoy5vwB)

Heavily inspired by [@user2390246's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157920/67312) to the related challenge. We need two sources of randomness: Changing the order of the colors and sampling the non-gray duck colors. The `sample` will take a random sample of random size given by an exponential distribution with rate parameter `1`, truncated to an integer. Using an exponential distrubtion unfortunately means that there is a probability of `exp(-8)` or around `0.0003354`  that the sample will be at least `8`, so we have to sample with `replace=T`.

Comment: you can replace then `\n` with an actual newline for 1

Comment: also you can save quite a bit using `colors()[c(26,254,498,552,640,652)]` in place of the `scan(..)` etc.  should come down to about 83

Comment: @MickyT ......... I don't use R's graphics enough to remember about all the nice graphics builtins like `colors()`! Those are some nice golfs, which I think you should post as your own answer, since this is the less elegant way of getting the colors.

Comment: ok then, I'll post it up with a couple of little changes

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>68</s> 64 bytes

```
`'DYCIXMSQ(qm#Q$4{#is,Gh1(=lAjUSId;&'F2Y232hZaYb8YrX)' duck'h7Mq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P0HdJdLZM8I3OFCjMFc5UMWkWjmzWMc9w1DDNscxKzTYM8VaTd3NKNLI2CgjKjEyySKyKEJTXSGlNDlbPcPct/D/fwA)

## Explanation

```
`                         % Do...while
  'DYCI···Id;&'           %   Push this string (to be decompressed by base conversion)
  F                       %   Push false
  2Y2                     %   Push string 'abc...xyz'
  32                      %   Push 32 (ASCII for space)
  h                       %   Concatenate horizontally. Gives 'abc...xyz '
  Za                      %   Base-convert from alphabet of all printable ASCII
                          %   characters except single quote (represented by input
                          %   false) to alphabet 'abc...xyz '. Produces the string
                          %   'grey red ··· violet'
  Yb                      %   Split on space. Gives a cell array of strings
  8Yr                     %   Random integer from 1 to 8, say k
  X)                      %   Get the content of the k-th cell
  ' duck'                 %   Push this string
  h                       %   Concatenate horizontally
  7M                      %   Push k again
  q                       %   Subtract 1
                          % Implicit end. Run a new iteration if top of the stack
                          % is non-zero
                          % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 98 bytes

**Look ma no imports!**

```python
v=0
while 1:x=id(v)%97%8;print"GVIYORGBrinererleodladeuyliln ee egog n  towe"[x::8],"duck";v=1/x,v
```

(Prints extra spaces between the colours and `duck` as allowed in the question)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8zWgKs8IzMnVcHQqsI2M0WjTFPV0lzVwrqgKDOvRMk9zDPSP8jdCchJLUotyknNT8lJTEktrczJzMlTSE1VSE3PT1fIU1AoyS9PVYqusLKyiNVRSilNzlayLrM11K/QKfv/HwA)**

A pretty poor pseudo-random number generator seeded with the object id of **0** (but it seems to fit the spec) which repeatedly yields an integer, `x`, in **[0,7]** which is used to slice a list of characters from that index in steps of **8** to get the colour name which is printed along with `duck` as a tuple, forcing a space in-between. When `x` becomes zero `Grey` is printed and the evaluation of the next input to the modulo based random number generator errors attempting to divide by zero (`v=1/x,v` tries to make a new tuple with the first element `1/x` = `1/0`)

---

Same way is 100 in Python 3 with

```python
v=0
while 1:x=id(v)%17%8;print("GVIYORGBrinererleodladeuyliln ee egog n  towe"[x::8],"duck");v=1/x,v
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 287 bytes

```java
Random r=new Random();int i;String c;do{i=r.nextInt(8);switch(i){case 0:c="Red";break;case 1:c="Orange";break;case 2:c="Yellow";break;case 3:c="Green";break;case 4:c="Blue";break;case 5:c="Indigo";break;case 6:c="Violet";break;default:c="Gray";}System.out.println(c+" duck");}while(i!=7)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc9NS8QwEAbgs/srxp5axOK3YujFi@xBhF0QZPGQTcbutGlSkunWpfS319bioafhfeYDppBHeVnocqCqdp6hGHPaMJl0I612lVgpI0OAN0kWutVZ3ewNKQgseSxHRxqqsRVv2ZPNd18gfR4S6IZ5HXxmsYU5xIkgy0BiHgYltOso86nFH15bjp8SEVpidYgp6ZQMCFfPKos2qCOx9yhL8YfXE757aXNc@M3kn2iMaxd@O/mrR7QLvpv4xTTLI/eTrq2m3C38YfIPcgb53zV@y8bwfF2eItFvT4GxSl3DaT2@yMbG6iIC3agySkTfHshgTOfZYzKIvh9@AQ)

My very first codegolf! Obviously not competitive, just happy to have learned enough Java (currently in CS200) to be able to participate.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

Could probably be shorter but my tool for finding the optimal permutation of the string to compress is crapping out on this, for some reason.

```
_èSiy}a@P±` Ýõ
`i`gÎ9h½uehéHÃÎÁeâ¸©ºÄgohgyËB`qh ö
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=X+hTaXl9YUBQsWAg3fUKYGlgZ845aL11ZWjpikjDzsFl4ripusQBZ29oZ5x5y0JgcWgg9g==&input=)

1 byte saved thanks to Oliver

Comment: [52 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=X+hTaXl9YUBQsWAg3fUKYGlgZ845aL11ZWjpikjDzsFl4ripusQBZ29oZ5x5y0JgcWgg9g==&input=)

Comment: Thanks, @Oliver. Did you brute force that?

Comment: Your tool only works with six items, so I excluded `red` and `grey` (shortest length), ran it through your tool, then added `red` and `grey` to the final list.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 86 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
{×⍵:∇r⊣⎕←'Grey' 'Red' 'Orange' 'Yellow' 'Green' 'Blue' 'Indigo' 'Violet'[r←?8]'duck'}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sPT3/Uu9XqUUd70aOuxUBxoKi6e1FqpbqCelBqCpD0L0rMS08FMiJTc3Lyy4EMoHRqHpB2yikFiXvmpWSm5wMZYZn5Oakl6tFFQDPsLWLVU0qTs9VrDf//BwA)

Assumes `⎕IO←0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 122 bytes

```
while({x:Any->println("$x duck");x!="Grey"}("Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Grey".split(",").shuffled()[0])){}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu9CsIwFEb3PkUMDgnE4lxR0EWcBAVBxCHYmzb0elvS9I/SZ4/BD850zlfVHi0F0xH7akui1067gkXa7O6dpULOCYszQiZLkvQamdnPYSgtgpjH7EjT5tDE0CMJvh5Z3n0qLnfjas/PDia@CH6DXF2dpgLUExDrQUUDpE7YgbpQbotaPWyN4NX/krYNWi@44jJty84YhFzI1/Yt5byEJfwA)

Comment: Might be helpful to someone out there, to get a random integer value in Kotlin, You can use the following:
    (0..7).shuffled()[0]

Shorter than:
    (Math.random()*8).toInt()

Answer (score 2):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), <s>195</s> <s>185</s> 184 bytes

```
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(9)=''WHILE @<>'Grey'BEGIN SELECT @=c FROM(VALUES('Red'),('Orange'),('Yellow'),('Green'),('Blue'),('Indigo'),('Violet'),('Grey'))v(c)ORDER BY NEWID()PRINT @+' Duck'END
```

Comment: Nice variation. You can remove the space before `BEGIN`.

Answer (score 2):

## MS-SQL, 158 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(6)a:SELECT @=value FROM STRING_SPLIT('Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Grey',',')ORDER BY NEWID()PRINT @+' duck'IF @<>'Grey'GOTO a
```

Based largely on [Razvan's excellent answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159627/70172), but using the `STRING_SPLIT` function that is specific to MS-SQL 2016 and later. Also uses a `GOTO` instead of a `WHILE` loop.

Formatted:

```sql
DECLARE @ VARCHAR(6)
a:
    SELECT @=value FROM 
        STRING_SPLIT('Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Grey',',')
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    PRINT @+' duck'
IF @<>'Grey'GOTO a
```

Answer (score 2):

x86_64 machine code, 120 bytes.

I got inspired by the 6502 machine code and implemented the same in x86_64 machine code.

```
0x603000: 0x47    0x72    0x61    0x79    0x20    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x603008: 0x52    0x65    0x64    0x20    0x00    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x603010: 0x4f    0x72    0x61    0x6e    0x67    0x65    0x20    0x00
0x603018: 0x59    0x65    0x6c    0x6c    0x6f    0x77    0x20    0x00
0x603020: 0x47    0x72    0x65    0x65    0x6e    0x20    0x00    0x00
0x603028: 0x42    0x6c    0x75    0x65    0x20    0x00    0x00    0x00
0x603030: 0x49    0x6e    0x64    0x69    0x67    0x6f    0x20    0x00
0x603038: 0x56    0x69    0x6f    0x6c    0x65    0x74    0x20    0x00
0x603040: 0x64    0x75    0x63    0x6b    0x0a    0x00    0x0f    0x31
0x603048: 0xc1    0xe8    0x03    0x33    0xdb    0x83    0xc3    0x07
0x603050: 0x23    0xd8    0x8b    0xfb    0xc1    0xe7    0x03    0x48
0x603058: 0x81    0xc7    0x00    0x30    0x60    0x00    0xe8    0x73
0x603060: 0xd5    0xdf    0xff    0x48    0xc7    0xc7    0x40    0x30
0x603068: 0x60    0x00    0xe8    0x67    0xd5    0xdf    0xff    0x85
0x603070: 0xdb    0x0f    0x85    0xcf    0xff    0xff    0xff    0xc3
```

Or the disassembly:

```
   0x603046:  rdtsc  
   0x603048:  shr    eax,0x3
   0x60304b:  xor    ebx,ebx
   0x60304d:  add    ebx,0x7
   0x603050:  and    ebx,eax
   0x603052:  mov    edi,ebx
   0x603054:  shl    edi,0x3
   0x603057:  add    rdi,0x603000
   0x60305e:  call   0x4005d6 <printf>
   0x603063:  mov    rdi,0x603040
   0x60306a:  call   0x4005d6 <printf>
   0x60306f:  test   ebx,ebx
   0x603071:  jne    0x603046
   0x603077:  ret
```

The first 70 bytes is a string table that looks like:

```
Gray\0\0\0\0
Red\0\0\0\0\0
Yellow\0\0
...
 duck\0
```

There is certainly room for optimizations and it might not be the shortest implementation in terms of bytes but it probably competes for least amount of bytes executed :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 49 bytes

```
λ`⟇∴ ɾ⟩ °√ ×ŀ ⟇↵ ¯Ǔ⋏ġ Vio⟇» ←√`⌈℅:` ¦ø`+,‛←√≠[x|¤
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CE%BB%60%E2%9F%87%E2%88%B4%20%C9%BE%E2%9F%A9%20%C2%B0%E2%88%9A%20%C3%97%C5%80%20%E2%9F%87%E2%86%B5%20%C2%AF%C7%93%E2%8B%8F%C4%A1%20Vio%E2%9F%87%C2%BB%20%E2%86%90%E2%88%9A%60%E2%8C%88%E2%84%85%3A%60%20%C2%A6%C3%B8%60%2B%2C%E2%80%9B%E2%86%90%E2%88%9A%E2%89%A0%5Bx%7C%C2%A4&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>96</strike> 91  bytes

```
until[n: random 8 print[pick[Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Grey]n"duck"]n = 8]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxCsJAEAXQ3lN8coG0QbCxESvBQpBlC8l8wpDJbFh3CZ5@jVg/Xqa0OyXEQ365pKV/kwJPW190Yate1IIf8VcMWLN6CauOc9gfbjtMxJNmacMlk46zVeLqolPCQ5Ox/OATvZM6zl10nDDE1r4)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+WIN, 106 bytes

```
⊃('red' 'orange' 'yellow' 'green' 'blue' 'indigo' 'violet' 'grey')[(↑(m=8)/⍳⍴m)↑m←1+8|n←1E3?1E3],¨⊂' duck'
```

Generates a vector of random integers between 1 and 8 and takes the series up to and including the first occurance of an 8 as indices into the colour vector and then concatenates the duck.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>138</s> <s>133</s> <s>123</s> 122 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to @ceilingcat

```c
*c[]={"Grey","Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Violet"};main(i){for(;printf("%s duck\n",c[i=time(sleep(1))%6])*i;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/18rOTrWtlrJvSi1UklHKSg1BUj6FyXmpacCGZGpOTn55UAGUDo1D0g75ZSCxMMy83NSS5RqrXMTM/M0MjWr0/KLNKwLijLzStI0lFSLFVJKk7NjgBqSozNtSzJzUzWKc1JTCzQMNTVVzWI1tTKtNa1r//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, <strike>166</strike>, <strike>148</strike>, <strike>142</strike> 98 Bytes

Down to 98 bytes thanks to Shaggy and Titus.

I tried a recursive solution.

```
function f(){echo[grey,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet][$n=rand()&7]." duck 
 ";$n&&f();}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f(){
  echo[grey,red,orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet][$n=rand()&7]
  //a line break goes here, thats why it skips a line after duck
  //saves one byte over \n
        ." duck
         ";
  $n&&f();
}
```

For real it does not need much, the function will stop when `$n == false` or as php asumes `$n == 0` as a `false` then it leaves the method.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##FY1BCoMwEEX3PUUQCQrTbruw0oOIiE3GGBpmQkxapPTqTePmLT6P//zq8@3uC5dEKlomsTTtB9XKgwm4Q0ANHGYyCDs6x28oMxI8XEKwpK1heFl2GMehpr6YumnldbxUQif1PFVdTVKWz@6bD@Yf@yOz5bMW28ohTuyRpjibnukP)

Don't really know how to "golf code", but i found this forum really, really fascinating.

Comment: the php tag was missing :D

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I think I see a few potential savings but I'll let those more proficient in PHP steer you better. @AJFaraday, you're missing the first line.

Comment: @Shaggy I didn't, if you take a look at the edit history, it initially didn't have the php tag.

Comment: Replace `' Duck'.PHP_EOL` with `" Duck\n"` to save a few bytes, for starters.

Comment: Do i need to set something else on tio.run?, if i do that the output is "Violet Duck\nGreen Duck\nRed Duck\nGray Duck\n"

Comment: mmm the if else is unnecesary, as on php 0 is intepreted as false.

Comment: Note the double, rather than single, quotes ;) Got it down to [103 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY1BCoMwEEX3PUUQEYVp6a4LKz2IFbHJmISGmRCTFim9elPd/MXj8b43Pufr7TAnktEyibluPigN9zrgCgEVcJhII6zoHL9hw0jwcAnBkrKa4WXZYRz6krrNVPUZLs1wKoRK8nmnoi2pqrZq@8375h/7/WjJRyUWwyGO7JHGOOmO6Q8).

Comment: I would never ever woulda found this `$n&&f();`

Comment: [101 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY1BCoMwEEX3PUUQEYVp6a4LKx5ERGwyJqFhJsSkRUqv3lQ3f/F4vO@Nz/neL4lktExiqZsPSsODDrhBQAUcZtIIGzrHb9gxEjxcQrCkrGZ4WXYYx6GkbjdVfYVbM14KoZJ8noq2pKrao@03H5t/7I@fNZ@VWA2HOLFHmuKsO6Y/)

Comment: [99 using the header](https://tio.run/##FY1BCoMwEEX3PUUQEYVp6a4LKx5ERKwZk9AwE2LSIqVXbxo3b/F5/Oe0S/feZa6RlmCYxFo3H1w0D8rjDh4lsJ9JIexoLb8hz0jwsBHBkDSK4WXYYhiHkrpsyvoKt2a8FELG5Xkq2pKqKp@233Qw/dgdnS2dpdg0@zCxQ5rCrDqmPw)

Comment: Drop `<?php` at all and invoke it with `cat prog.php | php -r`

Comment: `rand()&7` saves one more byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>40</s> <s>39</s> 38 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
]"sω2a⁄Ξ┌┼0⁾    a║EΣ?GΘƨ+}‘θJ;7ψ:≥w⁽OX@oo
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTVEJTIycyV1MDNDOTJhJXUyMDQ0JXUwMzlFJXUyNTBDJXUyNTNDMCV1MjA3RSUwOWEldTI1NTFFJXUwM0EzJTNGRyV1MDM5OCV1MDFBOCslN0QldTIwMTgldTAzQjhKJTNCNyV1MDNDOCUzQSV1MjI2NXcldTIwN0RPWEBvbw__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, 72 bytes<sup>(SBCS)</sup>

```
K" Duck"#=kOc." y9Fª¹Ú¹«·.Û»õx¾jL[`ýõ?;ß¼<|9ü"\ +kKIqk"Gray"B
```

[Try it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22+Duck%22%23%3DkOc.%22+y%019F%C2%AA%C2%B9%C3%9A%C2%B9%C2%AB%C2%B7%07.%C3%9B%C2%BB%C3%B5x%C2%BEj%1AL%5B%60%C3%BD%C3%B5%01%3F%3B%C2%80%C3%9F%1E%C2%BC%3C%C2%9F%04%7C9%C3%BC%1A%13%13%22%5C+%2BkKIqk%22Gray%22B&debug=0)

Python 3 translation:

```
import random
K=" Duck"
while True:
    k=random.choice("Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Gray".split())
    print(k+K)
    if k=="Gray":
        break
```

Comment: 65 bytes: [Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%23%3DkOc.%22+y%11%C2%81%C2%98an%C2%AA%C2%B3%C3%80A%5D%C3%B9A%2C%C3%A6%1Fq%7C%C2%A1%C2%BA%C3%86F%C3%BAE%C3%9E%C2%96x%28%C2%93%C2%89%C3%B3%C2%B0%C3%A0%27%C3%90%0E3%C3%AE%226%2Bk%22+duck%22I%7D%22ay%22kB&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [T-SQL](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server), <s>211</s> 178 bytes

```
SELECT c+' Duck'FROM(SELECT TOP(CAST(RAND()*9AS INT))c FROM(VALUES('Red'),('Orange'),('Yellow'),('Green'),('Blue'),('Indigo'),('Violet'))v(c)ORDER BY NEWID()UNION SELECT'Grey'c)q
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/8314)

Comment: Nice work, I couldn't figure out how to make `TOP` vary like that. You can save 2 bytes by removing the spaces after `' Duck'` and after `RAND()*9`.

Comment: Also, looks like its sorting the other colors by name, you could keep the randomness (and save bytes) by removing the outer sort entirely, and simply changing the order of your `UNION`: `...FROM(SELECT TOP...ORDER BY NEWID()UNION SELECT'Grey'c)q`

Comment: @BradC: Good advices, thanks! Although UNION without ORDER BY does not guarantee ordering, it's probable that the order will be correct, because for few rows it's unlikely to get a parallel execution plan.

Comment: Yep, seems unlikely in this small dataset. [This answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/634196/21398) that a `UNION ALL` is more likely to not change the order, but doesn't link to any sources.

Answer (score 1):

## [Swift](http://rextester.com/l/swift_online_compiler), <strike>161</strike> 143 bytes

```
import Foundation;var x=9;while x>0{x=time(nil)%7;print(["Grey","Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet"][x]+" duck");sleep(1)}
```

Thanks to [@cleblanc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159589/13448), whom I got the idea of the shorter code from.

**Explanation**

```
import Foundation                   //we need Foundation for time

var x = 9

while x > 0 {
    x = time(nil)%7
    print(["Grey",
           "Red",
           "Orange",
           "Yellow",
           "Green",
           "Blue",
           "Indigo",
           "Violet"][x] + " duck") //subscripting color array, appending "duck"
            sleep(1)
}
```

[Try it online!](http://rextester.com/VWLAIA73995)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 127 bytes

```python
from random import *;x=''
while'Grey'!=x:x=choice('Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet,Grey'.split(','));print(x,'duck')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxDsIgEIDh3aeo04G5uLjZsLiYTiYOJo6mnOUi5QjSlD49Eqd/@b@4ZSfhVOs7ydylV7AtPEdJuTv0xQDsVsee4Jpog70p52JGJzySgjtZvDUyET7Je1mxTRTw4hfCIVieBB8snjL@9fEbPWcFCFr3MXHIqiDYZfyArvUH)

Comment: FYI a very standard Python tip is to use `from module import*` and then just `thing` rather than `module.thing` here it will save 1 byte -- exceptions are when `module` is length four of less (e.g. `import os;os.wait(1)`) or there are multiple imports being made, when choices between modules should be made and `as` may come into play.

Comment: You could swap `x!='Grey` to `'Grey'!=x` to save one (the space). You could use no arguments for `split()` to save 3 (splits on spaces). You could use the allowance of any casing of output to go from `'Grey'!=x` to something like `'a'<x` to save four more... All in all my tips will save you 9 bytes [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##DcqxCsIwEADQvV9x2yUiLm5KHVzESXAQHEtzJodpLpwpTb8@dnrLy2sJko6tfVQm0CG5DZ6yaNl1tUfslsCRcMBLPdV@DMIjGXySg8e2PcGbYpQFbkqU4Bpngnty7AVeLJEKeKUVD78cuRhrz1k5FVP36Obxi7a1Pw) - it doesn't get you under other Python answers but good things for future golfing IMO anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6/Rakudo](https://perl6.org/) 78 bytes

```
say $_=<Grey Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet>.roll~" duck"until /y/
```

Stealing directly from [Dom Hastings' Perl 5 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159571/14710)

Perl 6 wins slightly with `.roll`

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>134</s> 116 bytes

```
DIM C$[8]C=RND(8)COPY C$,@L@L?C$[C];" duck
EXEC!C
DATA"Gray","Red","Orange","Yellow","Green","Blue","Indigo","Violet
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 124 bytes

```python
import random
b=1
while b>0:b=random.randint(0,7);print('Gray Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet'.split()[b],'duck')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5crydaQqzwjMydVIcnOwCrJFiKsB6Iy80o0DHTMNa0LikBMdfeixEqFoNQUBX@gbHqqQmRqTk5@uYJ7UWpqnoJTTmmqgidQU3q@Qlhmfk5qibpecUFOZomGZnRSrI56Smlytrrm//8A)

I almost always accompany my posts with explanations, but this one seems simple enough that I feel confident going without one...

Answer (score 1):

## F#, 171 bytes

```
let r=System.Random()
let mutable i=r.Next(8)
while i<>7 do
 printfn"%s duck"["Red";"Orange";"Yellow";"Green";"Blue";"Indigo";"Violet"].[i]
 i<-r.Next(8)
printf"Grey duck"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY09C8IwFEX3/opHQKiDxU3BtoMg4qJSQZDSITavNZgPSVNrf31M7OL0Lufyzm26Ra0NujLdKWvGs@bK5lUk0IKkXAE17RsyBwGY7DJ2FmVSUMW0jOfRD8ve0rtA4JlJjvix8doXw4MHlOYrYDoCeBkvbhSZdcD6@klKUiAjG3IyVLXoww2F0IMPe4Oo/N2KPvCDYrzVPly59mukSkpeeSFPF39zkz78jpPfwdJ9AQ)

That flipping "mutable" keyword! I thought that F#'s lack of a do/while loop (it only has while/do) would hurt me, but on retrospect it worked out, since "Grey duck" is always printed without a line separator (printfn versus printf), so there's no trailing empty line.

Answer (score 1):

## Visual Basic for Applications, <del>110</del> 102 bytes

Edit: saved eight more bytes by using `split()` instead of `array()`

```
while rnd>.3:?split("Red,Orange,Yellow,Green,Blue,Indigo,Violet",",")(rnd*6)+" duck":wend:?"Gray duck"
```

Type in the immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 104 bytes

```c
f(n){for(;printf("%.6s duck\n","Gray\0 OrangeYellowIndigoVioletGreen\0Blue\0 Red"+(n=time(0)%7)*6),n;);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCgIhFAB/RYSFZ23haTtIl70snYIOQbAX0adI7jPMJSL6drPrMMyYnTemVgckPi5lUI8cqDjg3X54Mrua@0y851PW71myc9bk8YYxpteJbPDpGlLEMmVEmuUYV2zWBS3fAh1LWBCk6A5iM4ielFDf2uJs0YGg7eAPfg)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 80 bytes

```
Repeat not(I
int(8rand→I
Disp sub("GRAY  RED   ORANGEYELLOWGREEN BLUE  INDIGOVIOLET",6I+1,6)+" DUCK
End
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + Coreutils, 100 Bytes

```
B=`shuf -en1 Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet Gray`;echo $B duck;[[ $B = Gray ]]||bash $0
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I think you have a little bit of unneeded whitespace in this answer. But I'm not an expert in Bash. Does `[[$B=Gray]]||bash $0` at the end work?

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>78</s> 87 bytes

```
-(e){RANDOM(0,1):{~Red|Orange|Yellow|Green|Blue|Indigo|Violet} duck|Gray duck->END}
->e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNVszrI0c/F31fDQMdQ06q6Lig1pca/KDEvPbUmMjUnJ7@8xr0oNTWvximnNLXGMy8lMz2/JiwzPye1pFYhpTQ5GyidWAlm6dq5@rnUcunapf7/DwA)

#### Explanation

```
-(e){RANDOM(0,1):{~Red|Orange|Yellow|Green|Blue|Indigo|Violet} duck|Gray duck->END}  // With a 50% chance of each, either pick a colour that hasn't been picked already (unless all others have also been picked) and print it followed by "duck", or print "Gray duck" and terminate.
->e   // if we haven't terminated we get here and go back to the line above
```

`+9 bytes`: Apparently shuffles in ink will not repeat an option until all options have been visited. This means the previous version of my program was not valid, since it would always encounter "gray" before it could encounter any other colour for the second time, and thus broke the "Colours can be repeated" rule. The new answer will print each non-gray colour once until all have been printed, then shuffle again and restart - except every time it's about to pick a colour there's a 50% chance it instead prints gray and terminates.