# Print random characters indefinitely

Tags: code-golf, random

### Task

---

Continuously print a random character `(a-z, A-Z, 0-9)` not separated by a newline (`\n`).

#### Expected output

---

```
b7gFDRtgFc67h90h8H76f5dD55f7GJ6GRT86hG7TH6T7302f2f4 ...
```

*Note: output should be randomised.*

### Requirements/Rules

---

1. Output must be continuous (i.e. never ending),
2. Output may not comprise of newlines,
3. Output must be random, and should not have a set seed (i.e: produce the same output every time)
4. Output must be only composed of characters: a-z, A-Z, 0-9.
5. **No loopholes**, regarding programming language version(s). Use only the tools available with that programming language, no third-party packages, modules, or other addons.

### Points

---

- Smallest file size (in bytes)

Comment: Like I [said in the Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges#comment75740_24111), I consider this to be a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/101638) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/13152/66833) and so I've closed this as a dupe of them

Comment: Things to avoid when writing challenges: [saying "random output" without further specification](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10909/78410), [assuming you've addressed sandbox feedback](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13040/78410).

Comment: Also, for future reference, I'd leave posts in the Sandbox for a *minimum* of 3 days - a week is usually a good rule of thumb. This allows multiple users to provide feedback, for you to address that and then for users to provide meta-feedback on any changes you then make

Comment: Not sure if it's been said yet, but welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Why am I getting upvotes??