# Am I divisible by double the sum of my digits?

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, decision-problem, division

Given a *positive* integer as input, your task is to output a truthy value if the number is [divisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) by the double of the sum of its digits, and a falsy value otherwise ([OEIS A134516](https://oeis.org/A134516)). In other words:

```
(sum_of_digits)*2 | number
```

- Instead of truthy / falsy values for the true and false cases, you may instead specify any finite set of values for the true/false case, and their complement the other values. For a simple example, you may use `0` for the true case and all other numbers for the false case (or vice versa, if you like).
- Standard input and output rules apply. Default Loopholes also apply.
- You can take input as an integer or as the string representation of that integer.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), hence the shortest code in bytes wins!
- I am new to PPCG, so I would like you to post an explanation if it's possible.

---

## Test Cases

```
Input - Output - (Reason)

80  - Truthy - (16 divides 80)
100 - Truthy - (2 divides 100)
60  - Truthy - (12 divides 60)
18 - Truthy - (18 divides 18)
12 - Truthy - (6 divides 12)

4 - Falsy - (8 does not divide 4)
8 - Falsy - (16 does not divide 8)
16  - Falsy  - (14 does not divide 16)
21 - Falsy - (6 does not divide 21)
78  - Falsy  - (30 does not divide 78)
110 - Falsy - (4 does not dide 110)
111 - Falsy - (6 does not divide 111)
390 - Falsy  - (24 does not divide 390)
```

Comment: Good challenge, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @Mayube Thanks, it is my second challenge, but the first one got closed :P

Comment: Are we allowed to take digits as a list of Integers?

Comment: @Henry No, that would be way too trivial

Comment: Would outputting `0` for `true` and any other number for `false` be allowed?

Comment: @Shaggy "The truthy / falsy values do not necessarily have to be constant, as long as for truthy you have a finite set of values, and their complement for the falsy ones." - so you have the set `{0}` for truthy and its complement,  `Z \ {0}` for false. Hence, I think it is allowed.

Comment: @Shaggy Sorry for the delay I answered: Yes, it is allowed.

Comment: Why does the truthy set have to be finite?

Comment: Indeed, the two sentences of "Instead of truthy / falsy values for the true and false cases, you may instead specify any finite set of values for the true case, and their complement for the falsy ones. For a simple example, you may use 0 for the true case and all other numbers for the false case (or vice versa, if you like)" seem to contradict each other (in particular, the "finite" and the "or vice versa").

Comment: @CalculatorFeline You can have the falsy set finite and its complement truthy

Comment: In my opinion, all calculate-able set should be accepted. (that is, there exists a Turing machine which, given an output, output True or False deterministically within a finite time.) For example, True = odd number, False = even number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/wiki/Code-Page)

```
ᚫ
```

Explanation:

```
      Implicitly convert to int array and sum the digits
 ᚫ     Double
     Is it a divisor of the input?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARUA6v9uZWlt///wnZCs4Zqr8J2Vnv//MTY)

[Detailed version](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCWsezlr9Ye7Uef/PzQvWUEjJLMtMSS1W0HQKhsopg0TzgUJ5@SVQaSTZ/4ZmAA)

Comment: Umm...you should check if the input is a multiple of double the sum of the digits, not vice versa.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer What do you mean? I do check if the input is a multiple of double the sum of the digits. Perhaps I did not explain it correctly.

Comment: Neim needs to get even golfier - when submissions get too long, my browser starts to lag.

Comment: @Challenger5 I sincerely apologise for the lack of golfiness. I will try again next time. Again, sorry about that.

Comment: @Okx And I sincerely apologize for being too lazy to find a Neim answer that was a better demonstration of what I was talking about.

Answer (score 15):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>31</s> <s>29</s> 27 bytes

Takes input as a string. Returns zero for truthy and non-zero for falsy.

```js
n=>n%eval([...n+n].join`+`)
```

#### Commented

```js
n => n % eval([...n + n].join`+`)
n =>                                   // take input string n  -> e.g. "80"
                  n + n                // double the input     -> "8080"
              [...     ]               // split                -> ["8", "0", "8", "0"]
                        .join`+`       // join with '+'        -> "8+0+8+0"
         eval(                  )      // evaluate as JS       -> 16
     n %                               // compute n % result   -> 80 % 16 -> 0
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>n%eval([...n+n].join`+`)

console.log('[Truthy]');
console.log(f("80"))
console.log(f("100"))
console.log(f("60"))
console.log(f("18"))
console.log(f("12"))

console.log('[Falsy]');
console.log(f("4"))
console.log(f("8"))
console.log(f("16"))
console.log(f("21"))
console.log(f("78"))
console.log(f("110"))
console.log(f("111"))
console.log(f("390"))
```

Comment: I've never seen the [...x] method of splitting before, is there a name for this specifically?

Comment: @JacobPersi This is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

Answer (score 7):

## C#, 46 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;n=>n%(n+"").Sum(c=>c-48)*2<1
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
using System;
using System.Linq;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<int, bool> f = n => n % (n + "").Sum(c => c - 48) * 2 < 1;

        Console.WriteLine(f(80));
        Console.WriteLine(f(100));
        Console.WriteLine(f(60));

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(f(16));
        Console.WriteLine(f(78));
        Console.WriteLine(f(390));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>38</s> 27 bytes

-11 bytes and fixed an error with the code thanks to @MartinEnder

```
$
$_¶$_
.+$|.
$*
^(.+)¶\1+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX4VLJf7QNpV4Lj1tlRo9LhUtrjgNPW3NQ9tiDLVV/v@3MOAyNDDgMgNSZlzmFlzGlkCWIRBbAAA)

Prints 1 if divisible, 0 otherwise

#### Explanation (hope I got this right)

```
$
$_¶$_
```

Appends the entire input, plus a newline, plus the input again

```
.+$|.
$*
```

Converts each match to unary (either the entire second line which is the original input, or each digit in the first line)

```
^(.+)¶\1+$
```

Check if the first line (the doubled digit sum) is a divisor of the second line

Answer (score 5):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 24 bytes

```
6A 0A 5E 31 C9 89 F8 99 F7 F6 01 D1 85 C0 75 F7 8D 04 09 99 F7 F7 92 C3
```

The above code defines a function in 64-bit x86 machine code that determines whether the input value is divisible by double the sum of its digits. The function conforms to the System V AMD64 calling convention, so that it is callable from virtually any language, just as if it were a C function.

It takes a single parameter as input via the `EDI` register, as per the calling convention, which is the integer to test. (This is assumed to be a *positive* integer, consistent with the challenge rules, and is required for the `CDQ` instruction we use to work correctly.)

It returns its result in the `EAX` register, again, as per the calling convention. The result will be 0 if the input value *was* divisible by the sum of its digits, and non-zero otherwise. (Basically, an inverse Boolean, exactly like the example given in the challenge rules.)

Its C prototype would be:

```
int DivisibleByDoubleSumOfDigits(int value);
```

Here are the ungolfed assembly language instructions, annotated with a brief explanation of the purpose of each instruction:

```
; EDI == input value
DivisibleByDoubleSumOfDigits:
   push 10
   pop  rsi             ; ESI <= 10
   xor  ecx, ecx        ; ECX <= 0
   mov  eax, edi        ; EAX <= EDI (make copy of input)

SumDigits:
   cdq                  ; EDX <= 0
   div  esi             ; EDX:EAX / 10
   add  ecx, edx        ; ECX += remainder (EDX)
   test eax, eax
   jnz  SumDigits       ; loop while EAX != 0
   
   lea  eax, [rcx+rcx]  ; EAX <= (ECX * 2)
   cdq                  ; EDX <= 0
   div  edi             ; EDX:EAX / input
   xchg edx, eax        ; put remainder (EDX) in EAX
   ret                  ; return, with result in EAX
```

In the first block, we do some preliminary initialization of registers:

- `PUSH`+`POP` instructions are used as a slow but short way to initialize `ESI` to 10. This is necessary because the `DIV` instruction on x86 requires a register operand. (There is no form that divides by an immediate value of, say, 10.)
- `XOR` is used as a short and fast way to clear the `ECX` register. This register will serve as the "accumulator" inside of the upcoming loop.
- Finally, a copy of the input value (from `EDI`) is made, and stored in `EAX`, which will be clobbered as we go through the loop.

Then, we start looping and summing the digits in the input value. This is based on the x86 `DIV` instruction, which divides `EDX:EAX` by its operand, and returns the quotient in `EAX` and the remainder in `EDX`. What we'll do here is divide the input value by 10, such that the remainder is the digit in the last place (which we'll add to our accumulator register, `ECX`), and the quotient is the remaining digits.

- The `CDQ` instruction is a short way of setting `EDX` to 0. It actually *sign-extends* the value in `EAX` to `EDX:EAX`, which is what `DIV` uses as the dividend. We don't actually need sign-extension here, because the input value is unsigned, but `CDQ` is 1 byte, as opposed to using `XOR` to clear `EDX`, which would be 2 bytes.
- Then we `DIV`ide `EDX:EAX` by `ESI` (10).
- The remainder (`EDX`) is added to the accumulator (`ECX`).
- The `EAX` register (the quotient) is tested to see if it is equal to 0. If so, we have made it through all of the digits and we fall through. If not, we still have more digits to sum, so we go back to the top of the loop.

Finally, after the loop is finished, we implement `number % ((sum_of_digits)*2)`:

- The `LEA` instruction is used as a short way to multiply `ECX` by 2 (or, equivalently, add `ECX` to itself), and store the result in a different register (in this case, `EAX`).

  <sup>(We could also have done `add ecx, ecx`+`xchg ecx, eax`; both are 3 bytes, but the `LEA` instruction is faster and more typical.)</sup>
- Then, we do a `CDQ` again to prepare for division. Because `EAX` will be positive (i.e., unsigned), this has the effect of zeroing `EDX`, just as before.
- Next is the division, this time dividing `EDX:EAX` by the input value (an unmolested copy of which still resides in `EDI`). This is equivalent to modulo, with the remainder in `EDX`. (The quotient is also put in `EAX`, but we don't need it.)
- Finally, we `XCHG` (exchange) the contents of `EAX` and `EDX`. Normally, you would do a `MOV` here, but `XCHG` is only 1 byte (albeit slower). Because `EDX` contains the remainder after the division, it will be 0 if the value was evenly divisible or non-zero otherwise. Thus, when we `RET`urn, `EAX` (the result) is 0 if the input value was divisible by double the sum of its digits, or non-zero otherwise.

Hopefully that suffices for an explanation.
This isn't the shortest entry, but hey, it looks like it beats almost all of the non-golfing languages! :-)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx)

```
SO·Ö
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/2P/Q9sPT/v@3MAAA)

You can also remove the last Ö to get 0 for truthy and something else for falsy resulting in only 3 bytes but to me that just doesn't seem to appropriately fit the definition.

#### Explanation

```
SO·Ö
SO    # Separate the digits and sum them
  ·   # Multiply the result by two
   Ö  # Is the input divisible by the result?
```

Comment: You can golf it to 4 bytes by replacing `%_` with `Ö`.

Comment: This was exactly what I was about to post... lol

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
tV!UsE\
```

Outputs `0` if divisible, positive integer otherwise. Specifically, it outputs the remainder of dividing the number by twice the sum of its digits.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L8kTDG02DXmv0vIfwsDLkMDAy4zIGXBZWjEZcIFpMy4jAy5zIEMQ6CwoSGXsaUBAA)

#### Explanation

```
t   % Implicit input. Duplicate
V!U % Convert to string, transpose, convert to number: gives column vector of digits
s   % Sum
E   % Times 2
\   % Modulus. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
{(2*+/10\x)!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlrDSEtb39AgpkJTsaL2f5qChcF/AA)

---

0 is truthy

Comment: Tacit but no shorter: ``!/|1(2*+/10\)\``

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 4 bytes

Takes input as a string. Outputs `0` for `true` or a number greater than `0` for `false`, which, from other solutions, would appear to be valid. If not, let me know and I'll rollback.

```
%²¬x
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=JbKseA==&input=IjM5MCI=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U`.
`"390"`

```
²
```

Repeat `U` twice.
`"390390"`

```
¬
```

Split to array of individual characters.
`["3","9","0","3","9","0"]`

```
x
```

Reduce by summing, automatically casting each character to an integer in the process.
`24`

```
%
```

Get the remainder of dividing `U` by the result, also automatically casting `U` to an integer in the process. Implicitly output the resulting integer.
`6 (=false)`

Comment: Your explanations usually use up a lot of vertical space, which I feel isn't needed. Either way, it's your answer.

Comment: @Okx; I don't know how "usual" it can be when I only switched to this format a couple of days ago.

Comment: I liked the explanation format. Was easy to follow, especially for this problem, as it was a linear reduction and moved down the page like a math problem. Just my two cents.

Comment: This explaination format is a lot better than the usual format, especially for those who are not familiar with the languages. I wish other golfers using these golfing languages would do this too.

Answer (score 3):

## C89, <strike>55</strike> 53 bytes

<sup>(Thanks to Steadybox!</sup>

```
s,t;f(x){for(t=x,s=0;t;t/=10)s+=t%10;return x%(s*2);}
```

It takes a single input, `x`, which is the value to test. It returns 0 if `x` is evenly divisible by double the sum of its digits, or non-zero otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdLNTsMwDAfwc/MUVlGlBArEYeoKITtx5gl6gX5ApJFOjTtVmvbspc2QuAVOvvzkvx2nvv2o63n2OemOT@LU9QMnM@XeSE2a7g1K4W8MZSj10NI4OJgy7q@V0Of5yrp6PzYtPHtqbH/3uWPMOoKvN@v4sbeNYCcGAMlhJM/TF3u03r7v26dUaJYchsV2PM2aisyuoqW6NAcoZQ4dL6WIIJQBLSWmoAiqiCMsQ6syjlRAakW/G1XutSf4516wWVtsojEQZvljlCKMUkSRwhUpjKJtSNtG4xAvL43xeyBeVDTw4TH0WsqqWPLzoaRm5/kb)

**Ungolfed:**

```
/* int */ s, t;
/*int */ f(/* int */ x)
{
    for (t = x, s = 0; t /* != 0 */; t /= 10)
        s += (t % 10);
    return x % (s * 2);
}
```

As you can see, this takes advantage of C89's implicit-int rules. The global variables `s` and `t` are implicitly declared as `int`s. (They're also implicitly initialized to 0 because they are globals, but we can't take advantage of this if we want the function to be callable multiple times.)

Similarly, the function, `f`, takes a single parameter, `x,` which is implicitly an `int`, and it returns an `int`.

The code inside of the function is fairly straightforward, although the `for` loop will look awfully strange if you're unfamiliar with the syntax. Basically, a `for` loop header in C contains three parts:

```
for (initialization; loop condition; increment)
```

In the "initialization" section, we've initialized our global variables. This will run once, before the loop is entered.

In the "loop condition" section, we've specified on what condition the loop should continue. This much should be obvious.

In the "increment" section, we've basically put arbitrary code, since this will run at the end of every loop.

The larger purpose of the loop is to iterate through each digit in the input value, adding them to `s`. Finally, after the loop has finished, `s` is doubled and taken modulo `x` to see if it is evenly divisible. (A better, more detailed explanation of the logic here can be found in [my other answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129740/58518), on which this one is based.)

**Human-readable version:**

```
int f(int x)
{
    int temp = x;
    int sum  = 0;
    while (temp > 0)
    {
        sum  += temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    return x % (sum * 2);
}
```

Comment: You can save two bytes, if you use [`t` instead of `t>0` as the loop condition](https://tio.run/##jdLNTsMwDAfwc/MUVlGlBArEYeoKITtx5gl6gX5ApJFOjTtVmvbspc2QuAVOvvzkvx2nvv2o63n2OemOT@LU9QMnM@XeSE2a7g1K4W8MZSj10NI4OJgy7q@V0Of5yrp6PzYtPHtqbH/3uWPMOoKvN@v4sbeNYCcGAMlhJM/TF3u03r7v26dUaJYchsV2PM2aisyuoqW6NAcoZQ4dL6WIIJQBLSWmoAiqiCMsQ6syjlRAakW/G1XutSf4516wWVtsojEQZvljlCKMUkSRwhUpjKJtSNtG4xAvL43xeyBeVDTw4TH0WsqqWPLzoaRm5/kb).

Comment: Ah, of course! Good catch, @Steadybox. Not sure how I missed that, since testing against 0 is exactly what my asm implementation did, on which this answer was heavily based.

Comment: [45](https://tio.run/##jdG/TsMwEAbwOX6KU1AkGwL4TJUGjDsx8wRZSv6ApeJUsVNFqvrsIXEHtoPplp/u@86u7z/rep59HnTHJ3Hu@oEHM@XeSD3p6dGgFP7OTBlKHTLjb5W@zDfW1YexaeHVh8b2D187xqwL8L23jp962wh2ZgCQHMfgefpmT9bbj0P7kgrNkuOw2I6nWVMFs6vCMl2aA5Qyh46XUhAIZUTLoBQUURU0wjKuKmmkIlIr@r2ocu99gH/eBZt1xYaMgdjljypFrFKQSOGKFJJoG9O2ZBzi9aWR/g/EqyIDn57jrmWsiiVDG8bBgdTsMv8A)

Answer (score 3):

## APL, 13 bytes

```
{⍵|⍨2×+/⍎¨⍕⍵}
```

Outputs `0` as a truthy value, and any other as falsy.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
ẹ+×₂;I×?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GundqHpz9qarL2PDzd/v9/Q7P/AA)

#### Explanation

```
ẹ+           Sum the digits
  ×₂         Double
    ;I×?     There is an integer I such that I×(double of the sum) = Input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Rod*

```python
lambda n:n%sum(map(int,`n`)*2)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCsIwEEbhvaf4N9JERkkr1FqqF1GhEQkONNNQ04WUnj3GzeNtvvCN71Gq5C73NFj/fFlIK9vP7JW3QbFE6qXXu0p3ZXLjBAYLbo0hlCan/k9NODWE49k82g0QpsxQLCv2VyxrccjO26iY4BRrnX4)

Comment: based on the example of "clearly distinguishable" provided in the question, I believe you can remove the `<1`.

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
(2Tr@IntegerDigits@#)∣#&
```

No clue why `∣` has a higher precedence than multiplication...

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

prints zero if divisible, positive integer otherwise.

```php
<?=$argn%(2*array_sum(str_split($argn)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkaKBkzWVvBxS0BYuoahhpJRYVJVbGF5fmahSXFMUXF@RklmiAJTU1Na3//wcA)

Comment: You put the assignment in the header block. You might as well use `$a=10`, but you forgot to count that towards your byte count

Comment: @aross why should I count the input towards to my byte count. `$argn` is available with the `-F` (in this case) or `-R` option

Comment: Hm, interesting. I didn't know about `-F`. But that's not reflected in your TIO (does it support echoing from STDIN?).

Comment: @aross it works like your approach use only a file instead of code and the `-F`option instead of `-R` http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php If you found an better way to make the same in tio like in the commnd line let me know

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 63 bytes

```
=MOD(A1,2*SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1,ROW(OFFSET(A$1,,,LEN(A1))),1)))=0
```

Summing digits is the lengthy bit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 19 bytes

```
{$_%%(2*.comb.sum)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiVeVVXDSEsvOT83Sa@4NFez9r@1QnFipUJ6UWoBUI2OQpyhgcF/AA)

Answer (score 2):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to Leo for saving 1 byte.*

```
Ṡ¦ȯ*2ṁis
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkPuoqfH/w50LDi07sV7L6OHOxszi////Rxsa6Rha6JgZ6FgY6BgaGOiY6FjoGJrpGBnqmAMZhkBBQ0MdY0uDWAA)

#### Explanation

```
Ṡ¦ȯ         Test whether f(x) divides x, where f is the function obtained by
            composing the next 4 functions.
       s    Convert x to a string.
     ṁi     Convert each character to an integer and sum the result.
   *2       Double the result.
```

Comment: You can use ṁ to map and sum with a single command, saving one byte

Answer (score 2):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>38</s> <s>37</s> 42 bytes

*Thanks to Zgarb for golfing off 1 byte*

```hs
f x=read x`mod`foldr((+).(*2).read.pure)0x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcyxDoMgAATQ3a@4EAeQlGgHZbHfIgkQTVEMasrfU12c8Ma7lxvV9jXOpWQR@2CURhxmrwfrnQ6UciZo9WbiWsR6BMPqmGY1LeihPdYwLTtKEFnj9QEB56Db6H9nZ6@WsAJ3bt3InG7kg26zus3rLvvdnd/pDw)

Takes input as a string; returns 0 if divisible and nonzero otherwise.

Comment: `(:[])` can be `pure`.

Comment: You will save 1 byte by replacing the lambda by function declaration

Comment: @bartavelle: Pretty sure it's a wash. Example?

Comment: You're right, it is the exact same length. Not sure how that crossed my mind :/

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 21 [bytes](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens)

-5 thanks to [@Oki](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60026/oki)

```
:fPart(Ans/sum(2int(10fPart(Ans10^(~randIntNoRep(1,1+int(log(Ans
```

This is made trickier by the fact that there is no concise way to sum integer digits in **TI-BASIC**. Returns `0` for `True`, and a different number for `False`.

Explanation:

```
:fPart(Ans/sum(2int(10fPart(Ans10^(-randIntNoRep(1,1+int(log(Ans
                               10^(-randIntNoRep(1,1+int(log(Ans #Create a list of negative powers of ten, based off the length of the input, i.e. {1,0.1,0.01}
                            Ans                                  #Scalar multiply the input into the list
                    10fPart(                                     #Remove everything left of the decimal point and multiply by 10
               2int(                                             #Remove everything right of the decimal point and multiply by 2
           sum(                                                  #Sum the resulting list
       Ans/                                                      #Divide the input by the sum
:fPart(                                                          #Remove everything left of the decimal, implicit print
```

Comment: `10^-randIntNoRep(1,1+int(log(Ans` does the same as `seq(10^(~A-1),A,0,log(Ans` in fewer bytes as order doesnt matter (Assuming version 2.55MP)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 35 bytes

```py
lambda a:a%(sum(map(int,str(a)))*2)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  You can remove some whitespace here.  Particularly around `=` and after the `)` in `int(c)`.  In addition since `sum` can take a generator as an argument you can remove the `[..]` inside it.  If you have any additional questions feel free to ping me.

Comment: `int(c)for c in a` could also be `map(int,a)`, to save a few bytes.

Comment: This doesn't work - or rather, works backwards. Easily fixed with 4 extra bytes: `lambda a:not a%(sum(map(int,str(a)))*2)`

Comment: @osuka_ see bullet point one in the question description

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 40 bytes

```java
i->i%(i+"").chars().map(k->k*2-96).sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY9NT8MwDIbv@xXWJKQE2qgtqGxD7MaBA@JQcUIcTNZu6UcSJe6kCe23lwQ2ThyQeKU4r53Yj9ziHlNja91uusmO772SIHv0Hp5QafiYQdCp7gkpXHujNjCEV1aRU3r7@gbotp6fPke1YaoYSfWiGbUkZbR41PSi0R2ebe2QjAML95NK1@qCqav5nAu5Q@cZFwNa1qXr7rJIlyUXfhwYn86D735BeHI1DhFQfTvTsEWWQJ6FUEazCKfgP61nfaEsF41xDyh3rDp4qkP7SKuVDZtRr/lfgTcJREqZQJEncBt9HtF5yK6X2X/gx9lx@gQ)

Returns 0 as truthy value and a value greater than 0 as falsy value.

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 11 bytes

```
L,EDEs;A@%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx9XFtdja0UFV8f///4YWAA)

First time I've used either a `L`ambda or `;` in an Add++ answer

### How it works

```
L,   - Create a lambda function. Example argument; 172
  ED - Push the digits;   STACK = [[1 7 2]]
  Es - Stack-clean sum;   STACK = [10]
  ;  - Double;            STACK = [20]
  A  - Push the argument; STACK = [20 172] 
  @% - Modulo;            STACK = [12]
  !  - Logical NOT;       STACK = [0]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <sup><s>6</s></sup> 5 bytes

```
¦DΣd¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@hZS7nFqcc2vn///9oCwMdQwMDHTMgZaFjaKRjogOkzHSMDHXMgQxDoLChoY6xpUEsAA)

-1 byte from Dominic Van Essen.

The existing answer doesn't use enough builtins, and Martin Ender is inactive, so I decided to post this.

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@hZS7nFqcc2vn///9oCwMdQwMDHTMgZaFjaKRjogOkzHSMDHXMgQxDoLChoY6xpUEsAA)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 37 bytes

```sh
for ((;i++<19;a+=2*s[i]))s=$1;((s%a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYi9CsMgEID3e4obLNzVxbMlTThDH6R0EKJEKA3EIaEvb52@n19dWyamlrcdibRYG2TSaGd/ra/yZq6zESWql8jcGI61fBLuKS546rJhRnNqCME8e31TGx2IczB0jCAe7tAxgBd4dJG@ReA2ufYH)

Outputs by exit code - 0 is falsey, 1 is truthy.

Explanation:

```sh
for ((;i++<19;a+=2*s[i]))s=$1;((s%a))    # i implicitly starts at 0
                         s=$1;           # set s to the input
for ((;                ))                # loop
          <19;                           #  while i is less than 19 (*)
       i++                               #  increment i
                   s[i]                  #  take the i'th character of s
                 2*                      #  doubled
              a+=                        #  add to a
                                s%a      # remainder of s divided by a
                              ((   ))    # output 0 if it's non-zero, 1 if it's zero
```

*(*19 is the length of the maximum integer zsh can handle)*

Answer (score 2):

## Swift, <s>53</s> 46 bytes

Takes in a `String` or [`Substring`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/substring) representing an integer in [1, 255].

```swift
{UInt8($0)!%($0.utf8.reduce(0){$0+$1-48}*2)<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@Z@TWqKQZqWgEVxSlJmXrqmga6fglJ@fo2D7vzrUM6/EQkPFQFNRFUjqlZakWegVpaaUJqdqGGhWqxhoqxjqmljUahlp2hjW/k/LL1LIVMjMUzDU09MzMjVVqOZSAIICoLElGkoxGpmaVgoxGmlQi4BcTU0lTa7a/wA)

Type information not included, since it could be either:

```swift
let f: (String) -> Bool = {UInt8($0)!%($0.utf8.reduce(0){$0+$1-48}*2)<1}
let g: (Substring) -> Bool = {UInt8($0)!%($0.utf8.reduce(0){$0+$1-48}*2)<1}
```

Swift [`Character`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character) is... weird. It's not a single byte, like in C (that's [`CChar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cchar)), but it's also not a single Unicode codepoint (that's [`Unicode.Scalar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar)). Rather, it represents an [extended grapheme cluster](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries). This makes certain oprations substantially more painful, but others substantially easier. For this reason, I access the string's `utf8` property (which is a collection of `UInt8`).

`String` and `Substring` are collections of `Character`; however, they also have a lot more shared functionality than e.g. `[Character]` because they conform to [`StringProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol), and are in fact the only types that conform to it. I thought `StringProtocol` would work as the input type, but then the type checker times out.

For 49 bytes, here's a version that accepts integers in [1, 2^31 - 1] or [1, 2^63 - 1] depending on the machine:

```swift
{Int($0)!%($0.utf8.reduce(0){$0+Int($1)-48}*2)<1}
```

#### Explanation/Ungolfed

```swift
{ (number: String) -> Bool in
    return
        UInt8(number)! // Convert String to UInt8, force-unwrap optional
            % (
                number.utf8 // Convert String to byte array
                    .reduce(0) { (prevResult: UInt8, nextChar: Character) -> UInt8 in
                        return prevResult + nextChar - 48
                        // Convert ASCII to number by subtracting 48; sum the results
                    } * 2
            ) == 0 // convert number to boolean
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
VR.Mvd&+2*c%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/8/LEjPtyxFTdtIK1k17////xYGAA)

Outputs 0 for truthy, any other number for falsey.

### Explanation

```
VR.Mvd&+2*c%  Implicit input from command-line args
VR            Create stack2, return to stack1
  .M          Duplicate input to stack2
    vd        Switch to stack2, split into digits
      &+      Sum up all digits
        2*    Double
          c   Collapse stack2 back into stack1
           %  Modulus
              Implicit output of last item on stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), 66 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Olivier

```java
a->{int i=0;for(int b:(""+a).getBytes())i+=b-48;return a%(i*2)<1;}
```

Ungolfed & explanation:

```java
a -> {
    int i = 0;

    for(int b : (""+a).getBytes()) { // Loop through each byte of the input converted to a string
        i += b-48; // Subtract 48 from the byte and add it to i
    }

    return a % (i*2) < 1 // Check if a % (i*2) is equal to one
    // I use <1 here for golfing, as the result of a modulus operation should never be less than 0
}
```

Comment: Use `int` instead of `byte` to save... a byte.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. Didn't notice that.

Comment: @Okx Need to change golfed code as well.

Comment: Your (golfed) code gives incorrect values for 110, 111. Probably the `a%i*2` that's parsed as `(a%i)*2` since modulus and multiplication have the same order.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ah, that sucks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
vUì x*2
```

Returns `1` for `true`, `0` for `false`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyz08BqFCi2j//8NDQwA)

### Explanation

```
vUì x*2
v        // Return 1 if the input is divisible by:
 Uì      //   Input split into a base-10 array
    x    //   Sum the array
     *2  //   While mapped by *2
```

Comment: I came up with a few other 7 byte solutions for this, too (although, I don't think this was one of them) - I'm convinced there's a shorter solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 Bytes

```
f x=(==) 0.mod x.(*)2.sum.map(read.return).show$x
```

**Usage**

```
f 80
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcohDoAgGAbQ7im@YADDPySohcOwAZMp4EAnt8eO9e3tuhz2PFtzqIopxSEoJINKbOKSyhMo6Itlqw1lez85cip7esfagvYRCiYNwJV9vEFwGLEJdDKLHy3/tPQi517WDUP7AA)

Comment: Tips: there is an extra space, return==pure, list comprehensions are often very compact : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcoxDkAwAAXQ3Sn@YEBC2g4Y9CRiaJRUqEpLdHD32tv15Snh9uU4QljhOeFcGwlfsMo9erSLkOM8ffNQO2Ve@KkMWmwnOKTJgMtu540GK3L0BJFQklCbpjYWRmPpemThBw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## J, 15 bytes

0 indicates truthy, nonzero indicates falsy.

```
|~[:+/2#"."0@":
```

Explanation

```
        "."0@":  convert to list of digits
  [:+/2#         sum 2 copies of the list ([: forces monadic phrase)
|~               residue of sum divided by argument?
```

Comment: Very clever way to avoid parens or multiple `@` or `[:`!

Comment: I debated posting this as my own answer, but it's not really different enough. `|~2*1#.,.&.":` for 13 bytes.

Comment: I get a 'domain error' for this on my J Qt IDE. (|~[:+/2#"."0@": 112)
Then for cole's code I get (|~2*1#.,.&.": 112)=0. :/ Possibly something wrong on my end.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 5 bytes

```
D}Σd¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/I/f/fpfbc4pRDS///N7QAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 45

```
puts [expr 1>$n%(2*([join [split $n ""] +]))]
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/VEPM37548)

Comment: You can replace `0==` with `1>`.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell, 39 bytes

```
($a="$args")%($a*2-replace'\B','+'|iex)
```

0 as Truthy output, any other number as Falsey.

```
PS D:\> D:\t.ps1 80
0

PS D:\> D:\t.ps1 81
9
```

It takes the args array as a string, does string multiplication to double all the digits, regex-replaces non-word-boundaries to make '8+0+8+0', eval's that to get the sum, and calculates a remainder of original/sum.

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9X0Ml0VZJJbEovVhJUxXI0TLSLUotyElMTlVX11HXNlCvyUyt0Pxfy8WlppKmYGEAoQz/AwA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") by changing the replace to `-replace'','+0'`, `80` would become `+08+00+08+00+0`

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <strike>35</strike> 34 bytes

```hs
f x=mod x$2*sum[read[c]|c<-show x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcoxCoAgAAXQvVP8wSkoqsEc6iTiIJkoaUYWOXR32219PCPjtjqXs0aafVBIZKjj7fm5SsUX8S5TE014kET20u6YoUIFHKfdL7TQIGAdCum7H9F/oqUMfSkjQ5U/)

Returns '0' in the true case, the remainder otherwise.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), pointfree edition by nimi, 34 bytes

```hs
mod<*>(2*).sum.map(read.pure).show
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzPzc/xUbLTsNIS1OvuDRXLzexQKMoNTFFr6C0KBUolJFf/j83MTNPwVYhJZ9LQaGgKDOvREFPIU1BRcHCQAFNxNAAQ8gMU5EZuoiRIbqIuYUC138A)

Comment: Same byte count if you go pointfree: `mod<*>(2*).sum.map(read.pure).show`

Comment: Looks good, I added it in my submission.

Answer (score 1):

## Mini-Flak, <s>296</s> 292 bytes

```
({}((()[()]))){(({}[((((()()()){}){}){}){}])({}(((({})){}){}{}){})[({})])(({}({})))({}(({}[{}]))[{}])({}[({})](({}{})(({}({})))({}(({}[{}]))[{}])({}[({})]))[{}])(({}({})))({}(({}[{}]))[{}])({}[({})])}{}({}(((({}){})))[{}]){({}((({}[()]))([{(({})[{}])()}{}]()){{}{}(({}))(()[()])}{})[{}][()])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVTLbtswEDxTX7HVRVITG7aTSx3k1nNatL0FOdASHQuRRYGi7LaCv92dXUoOEicB6re5y5md4S5XTpf1ZF3pp@Mx79yS4l/fvseUzBNKFnhf4X2d0Eye0@k0itL@oFRT5k/UNeQ3hrxtaL8pK0Nl3RrnOUulaZrdp9lDlinl95b@GmdNO6V4p12pV5VpLynXVWUK2umKdF1Q223jKIteVcG8b1fSK6XW1hmdb6goH0vfLsErL9Uf7vHJVaAOfmb94fRSCpSdoWSWIOlBqdzWOxQeUKCHQjye8e8v8VgoKotUBoL@wLjACngBl0HplpPoguazz/gbqXvOAgM/ysca1QIB9nXthrFbr/OnSMnXKJoBGAp2vCNcMbfQZ1IKxPYHOC2fANfOlwyw182lnBCv0MpUdk9lKyvOtP4VL3My90e8YBJBbHEqwpXi/AvRfUOFqYw38hsZZ/C12X@A/qGsEzUYf0LYW/CMK/jn2AEk@j@KQxR9tbWZ0h2Me8E2O53QyHBnfnvxecndkneV9uzyFtNVGIex4bb7YbZ2x8tFVxe69jTjaUpVg@MwDpFhFGR8Qldl0XisRddUZc6woTvtmguIojMbwHq74NoWEseYhOnk2KdbcCoZYfYPbXHiXlWWe1Glp1Bo2BDg2S4Lc54ulo6TLn09maCCGwnJEPbS/Gu5JwL/sGtQxutYpiUVtk48ugSzhuEY6U2uu9ZI2wbl6OEBBJTKGd@5mua8wrKU33Qt9z3ShtjKWvS2bj2bBrpL0pRXOFr@j6ZEvVOpVPYPTcx81uFGqOGbbIKNuGoAW6Mf5EIreNdDytJVbR75cIRr9Qdns/JO557Wzm5pLjcc2/OWIxT7jYbfKFvMYztiURgqamzThIsS6rddy8McBD8nkK2KIIVeeMylQQ/LPIW5L0JCuKOHg9Miiq33xm2hG3Lici2VHJ79caGL2Z/KrL1sQlROc7zlhloBJeM3sEwmWL7huToe54ur6@NE/wM)

The TIO link have more comments from me, so it is partially easier to read.

Truthy/Falsey: Truthy (divisible) if the second number is equal to the third number, falsy otherwise. So both the truthy and falsy set are infinite, but I suppose that should be allowed. +10 byte if that is not.

Note: Leading/trailing newlines/whitespaces are not allowed in input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```java
a->{int i=0,x=a;for(;x>0;x/=10)i+=x%10*2;return a%i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU89T8MwEN37K26plIBr7IBKwXIlRgbEUDFVHUzqVg6pbdmXkijKbw9OgJNO7z7fu6vUVa2c17Y6fo2@@axNCWWtYoQ3ZSz0C4C/akSFCa7OHOGSetkOg7Hn/QFUOMd8HgWoEh9t0NT01NgSjbP01eKHVaF79zoodAE8yFGttr2xCEYy0kolTi5kot0y0d5JznJzK9slZzeFCBqbYEEtjRhGmE3MSmkDsokCdcRnsPobUrY/9BtGOGNknWBDeEEeSII1KTh5TAFPZc7J/RMb/m8G2HUR9YW6BqlPT2FtM0@V93X3EtP52SSRg5TA8l/xYTH5MP4A)

A return value of `0` means truthy, anything else means falsy.

Since my comment in Okx's answer made no ripple, I deleted it and posted it as this answer, golfed even a bit more.

Further golfing thanks to @KrzysztofCichocki and @Laikoni who rightfully showed me I needn't answer a truthy/falsy value, but any value as long as I describe the result.

Comment: You can remove the <1 part at the end, so the result will be 0 for true and >0 for false, which is accebtable, this will result in additional -2 bytes, so you answer coiuld be like 53 bytes.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichoki No I can't: this is Java. The only truthy value is `true`.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire While this true if nothing else is specified, this challenge specifically states `Instead of truthy / falsy values for the true and false cases, you may instead specify any finite set of values for the true/false case, and their complement the other values.`.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki and Laikoni Sorry I misread that part, I just fixed it! Thank you both :) Also, sorry for [rejecting the edit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41628) which was actually appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 44 bytes

```
for(;~$d=$argn[$i++];)$t+=2*$d;echo$argn%$t;
```

Run like this:

```
echo 80 | php -nR 'for(;~$d=$argn[$i++];)$t+=2*$d;echo$argn%$t;'
```

## Explanation

Iterates over the digits to compute the total, then outputs the modulo like most answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 51 bytes

```cs
n=>{int l=n,k=0;for(;l>0;l/=10)k+=l%10;return n%k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdGxasMwEAbg2XqKWwI2TVPJ1JaMIi@FTOlQOnQ2qmqE1RNIcqEEP7vjpLP6ww3Hd/APp@Oj9sGsc7Q4wvtvTOZbEqLdECO8kQuBLTENyWr48fYTXgeLZQV/cMtpRn20mPbb9DCCghVVf9k2cAr3k6Lyy4dSup5K96QYraYH5XaMymDSHBBwN8lllaR48Ri9M4ePYJM5WzTlWNZVlZEmK11WmMgSzzexpuYd/Y@z1rZtvpHzrNWU5QtFJ7hoRfN8u1hIUdx/QZb1Cg)

0 for truthy, anything else for falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 + 1 (-p) = 22 bytes

```perl
$_%=eval s/./+2*$&/rg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXtU2tSwxR6FYX09f20hLRU2/KP3/f0NDg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Comment: -1 byte: `$_%=eval s//+2*/rg.0`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 10 bytes

```
nsS&+2*lf%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@vOFhN20grJ031/39DCwMA)

Ly is lucky enough to have a splitting built-in.

Returns 0 for truthy and a number greater than 0 for falsy.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - 12 Bytes

```
%sZ*2ssMscZ1
```

Explanation:

```
%       - implicitly print modulus of
 s      - parse int
  Z     - input
 *      - two times
  s    - sum of
   M   - map
    s  - parse int to
    c  - substrings
     Z - of input
     1 - of length 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 34 bytes

```
p&::v>0g2*%.@
+19:_^#:/+91p00+g00%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v0DNyqrMziDdSEtVz4FL29DSKj5O2Upf29KwwMBAO93AQPX/fyNjAA)

Prints 0 for truthy, a different integer for falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
f.&ẹj+∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/6fpqT3ctTNL@1FHx///0RYGOoYGBjpmQMpCx9BIx0QHSJnpGBnqmAMZhkBhQ0MdY0uD2P8A)

The predicate succeeds if the input is divisible by twice the sum of its digits, and fails otherwise. Run as a program, success prints `true.` and failure prints `false.`.

This started off as a minor edit to Fatalize's answer, golfing a byte off by replacing `+×₂` with `j+`, but as I was testing it I noticed that one or another of the updates he's made to the language in the last year and a half seems to have broken his solution on the case of 18, with `I` apparently being unable to assume the value of 1, so I ended up having to restructure it somewhat (fortunately without changing the byte count).

```
f.         The output variable is a list of the input's factors.
  &        And,
   ẹ       the digits of the input,
    j      all duplicated,
     +     sum up to
      ∈    a member of the output variable.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 11 bytes

```
i:'+A2*%0=@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TSl3b0UhL1cDW4f9/CwMA)

#### Explanation

```
i:             Read input, duplicate it
  '+A          Sum its digits
     2*        Multiply by 2
       %       Modulo input with digit sum
        0=     Compare to 0
          @    Print and terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 58 bytes

```forth
: f 0 over begin 10 /mod >r + r> ?dup 0= until 2* mod 0= ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBDoMwDEPv/QqLIxOsLRNjQ@v@ZUAZ0qBVBPv9kvTybMdJfKD9W81eJKUnPDTCfyJ8pnnZYDSuaxjhCBeQw3s8IvQLx7YvP9gSUnLu@TRCygY1oS6AyqHgd1byQOhVpxGV0cI2205gGQOpG0vOLcMaxj1HkzeNDJoH@3QC)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f           \ start a new word definition
  0 over      \ create an accumulator and copy the input above it on the stack
  begin       \ start an indefinite loop
    10 /mod   \ divide by 10 and get quotient and remainder
    >r + r>   \ add remainder to accumulator
    ?dup      \ duplicate the quotient if it's greater than 0
    0=        \ check if quotient is 0
  until       \ end the indefinite loop if it is
  2* mod      \ multiply result by 2, then modulo with input number
  0=          \ check if result is 0 (input is divisible by result)
;             \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg+Reg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 11 bytes

Boring algorithm.

```
¿:;9%1+2*%
```

Finds the [digital root](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Digital_root_calculator) of the top of the stack and then finds the remainder.

0 is a truthy value, any value that is not 0 is a falsy value. (Including ASCII characters)

### Explanation (Syntactically invalid)

```
¿#         Integer input
 :#        Duplicate
  ;9%1+#   Digital Root Formula (1+(n-1)mod 9)
       2*%#Multiply by 2 and find the remainder
```

I believe everyone here used repetition/reduction but not an existing formula.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
∑dœ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?s=?flags=&code=%E2%88%91d%C5%93&inputs=100&header=&footer=)

Compiles as:

```python
stack.push(summate(stack.pop()))
stack.push(stack.pop() * 2)
lhs, rhs = stack.pop(2); stack.push(int((rhs % lhs) == 0))
```

### Explained

```
∑dœ
∑   # Push the sum of the integers of the input
 d  # Double that sum
  œ # And push ((sum(input) * 2) % input) == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
Σ∞÷
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///c4kcd8w5v///fwoDL0MCAywxIWXAZGnGZcAEpMy4jQy5zIMMQKGxoyGVsaQAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ    # Get the digit-sum of the (implicit) input-integer
 ∞   # Double it
  ÷  # Check if the (implicit) input-integer is divisible by this value
     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 103 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][N
T   S S N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_DONE][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S T T   _Modulo][S T    S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd][T    S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  S T S N
_Push_10][T S T S _Integer_divide][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_DONE][T   T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S S N
_Multiply]{T    S T T   _Modulo][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Outputs `0` as truthy or a positive integer as falsey.

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIgYiTixMEuCACXJxQCQUFTiAEcjlBNIQJ0sSJJANSycUFFuXkhEmBTQBpAxrJ@f@/hQEA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

To output two distinct values (`0` for truthy; `1` for falsey) it would be **128 bytes** instead: [try it online](https://tio.run/##hVJBboMwEDzDK/KBSsAPosCBKgEUOBWhlRO7iSUSW8aERn089WJohUIaWT54d3ZnZ9bdmWvWSHJkfV/mKzyJC1nbnMGrSnzkKwhbWfMj0exZrHASt3AKB/aMUMiLME6ANMCvmp2YwvyY1YqzGzMJ2eqqxEYD30Yx7LQlB1bDNk2zRxpEF86Ijz/Bg/f2IkGLsSpMk2ipymrCSryTNn8YGmNmrJ2gbS0QaglG4EbIO3hvB9IwCsGV2go8sKbUcpnqvCM4hrmdeE1nimPrClB@45RZFxLXQOeCrA3WokeTrNwnvr6YbJoqmBSZwK6tNZf1vfpesGV5E7j0pU18RPv0j@7XAvtLMASZMj9j9kFQv0FGX1yDVOKkyGXSPrSYaQ/@a9X3vu//AA).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer sum = 0
Integer input = STDIN as integer
Integer n = input
Start LOOP:
  If(n == 0):
    Jump to Label DONE
  Integer t = n modulo-10
  sum = sum + t
  n = n integer-divided by 10
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

DONE:
  sum = sum * 2
  Integer result = input % sum
  Print result as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.text.utils math.unicode`, 37 bytes

```
[ dup 1 digit-groups Σ 2 * mod 0 = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYg9CsIwGIZ3T/HOgiWpUqviLC4u4iQOpfmswTaJyRdQxNN4H68Ug07Pz7lp2fp02G93myWu5A31GBq@FEx3LiLrPvz6P6PRrVUE54n54bw2jEC3SKalgNVo9EQtIIVAlVFDlpgho0IpMc8i85YS04XAKx2hooOE0p3mSedtdAGfN0qMMVgFgTVOaWgcivQF)

### Explanation

```
                ! 12
dup             ! 12 12
1 digit-groups  ! 12 { 2 1 }
Σ               ! 12 3
2 *             ! 12 6
mod             ! 0
0 =             ! t
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
∑dḊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJFk4biKIiwiIiwiMzkwIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 121 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
main(){std::string n;int m=0;std::cin>>n;for(char i:n){m+=i-48;};std::cout<<((stoi(n)%(m*2)==0)?0:1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcrRCsIgFIDh@55CiEAbgkUXQ6c9i5xtdmAex3R0MfbqWYxuv/@HeZYBoNYzEkxrP3SYclkGH90JqbDokbjYcum1/jlSYGSOYJU5FJCcIzOmhcPLLww1iS02FuWjNfv/SWvpOs5zSchJXHi83oW1SjyVvgmz19qqD4yTD7nK9xc)

## Explanation

```cpp
#include<iostream>
main(){
  std::string n; int m = 0; // Initialize `n` (input) and `m` (sum)
  std::cin >> n; // Get input
  for(char i:n) // Loop through input to calculate the sum of digits
  {
    m+=i-48;
  };
  std::cout<<((stoi(n)%(m*2)==0)?0:1); // Output `0` if double the sum of digits is divisible by the number, else return `1`
}
```

Comment: [109 bytes](https://tio.run/##LcpBCsMgEEDRfU8hlIK2CKF0EdR4F5kkdiCOQSd0EXL12lK6/LwP66ojQGtnJFi2cXKYK5cpJH9CYpFsCkhS7ZVHY76CFAXZXwGS92TnXCQ8QxFoSKXbgPrR/4e8sXOyckZJ6iLT9a58p@zRWt@9YV5CrE2/Pg "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 62 bytes

```
f(n)=0^{mod(n,2mod(floor(n/10^{[0...floor(logn)]}),10).total)}
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/064or4gwxp)

[Try It Online! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eowlencude)

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 39 bytes

```
;=n!=p=sE P;Ws;=n+*2%s 10n=s/s 10O!%p n
```

[Try it online!](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7PW4hPXA9c0UgUDtXczs9bisqMiVzIDEwbj1zL3MgMTBPISVwIG4iLCIzOTAiXQ==)

[Test Suite](https://knight-lang.netlify.app/#WyI7ID0gZiBCTE9DS1xuICAgIDs9biE9cD1zRXo7V3M7PW4rKjIlcyAxMG49cy9zIDEwISVwIG5cbjogV0hJTEUgKD0geiBQUk9NUFQpXG4gICAgT1VUUFVUICgrIHogKCsgJyAtPiAnIChDQUxMIGYpKSkiLCI4MFxuMTAwXG42MFxuMThcbjEyXG40XG44XG4xNlxuMjFcbjc4XG4xMTBcbjExMVxuMzkwIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 21 bytes

```arturo
$->n->n%2*∑digits n
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?RUGRqR)

Returns 0 for true or any other number for false.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
SḌḊ
```

##### Explanation

```
SḌḊ   # implicit input
S     # sum the digits
 Ḍ    # double this number
  Ḋ   # input is divisible by this?
      # implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 47 bytes

```lua
n=...a=0n:gsub('.',load'a=2*...+a')print(n%a<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/z1ZPTy/R1iDPKr24NElDXU9dJyc/MUU90dZICyijnaiuWVCUmVeikaeaaGOo@f//fzMDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
DSḤḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l@OGOJQ939P7//9/QwAAA)

Explanation:

```
DSḤḍ Takes an integer as input.
D    Get digits (convert to base 10)
 S   Sum
  Ḥ  Unhalve (double)
   ḍ Check if y (the input itself) is divisible by x
```

Comment: @TheIOSCoder Added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 24 bytes

```
n->!(n%(2*sumdigits(n)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P105RI09Vw0iruDQ3JTM9s6RYI09TU/N/YkFBTqVGnoKunUJBUWZeCZCpBOIoKaSBFOgoRFsY6CgYGgAJMxDDTEfB3EJHwdjSIFbzPwA)

Answer (score 0):

## jq, 37 characters

```
.%(tostring/""|map(tonumber)|add*2)<1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq '.%(tostring/""|map(tonumber)|add*2)<1' <<< '60'
true

bash-4.4$ jq '.%(tostring/""|map(tonumber)|add*2)<1' <<< '390'
false
```

[Try on jp‣play](https://jqplay.org/s/RVbg5K73FI)

Answer (score 0):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [@Challenger5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/challenger5)*

```
{_Ab:+2*%}
```

Anonymous block that takes the input from the stack and replaces it by the output, which is `0` if divisible or a positive integer otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1vYfC/Ot4xyUrbSEu19n8dkA8A) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vzreMclK20hLtfZ/tIWBgqGBgYIZkLJQMDRSMFEAUmYKRoYK5kCGIVDY0FDB2NIgVrXgv4UBAA).

#### Explanation

```
{        }   e# Block
 _           e# Duplicate
  Ab         e# Convert to base 10. Gives an array of digits
    :+       e# Fold addition over array
      2*     e# Multiply by 2
        %    e# Modulus
```

Comment: You can replace `s:~` with `Ab` (convert to base 10)

Comment: @Challenger5 Thanks! Edited

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + coreutils + bc, 46 bytes

```
yes $1%\(0`echo $1|sed 's/\(.\)/+\1*2/g'`\)|bc
```

Input via command line.  0 is truthy.

First I tried to loop through the characters of the input string, but bash loops are to big.  I ended up using sed to replace each character with an addition and multiplication, which then goes to bc. I saved a byte using yes instead of echo.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 27 bytes

```
$_%(2*eval join'+',split//)
```

Returns 0 for Truthy and non-zero for Falsy

Comment: Welcome on the site. Answers need to be either full programs or functions, while your answer is only a snippet. To make it a full program, you could add `-p` flag (cost 1 byte), and start with `$_%=(2*...)`. Also, `join'+',split//` can be simplified to `join'+',@F` is you use `-F ` flag, or even better, `s/./+$&/gr` :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 25 bytes

```ruby
->x{x%(x.digits.sum*2)<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukJVo0IvJTM9s6RYr7g0V8tI08aw9n9BaUmxQlq0hUEsF5RpEvsfAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [LOGO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fmslogo/), 24 bytes

```
[modulo ? 2*reduce "+ ?]
```

<s>Try it online!</s>
Only FMSLogo and its older version (MSWLogo) support `?` in template-list; and only FMSLogo supports `apply` for infix operator `+`.

That is a template-list (equivalent of lambda function in other languages).
Return 0 for truthy and other values for falsy.

Usage:

```
pr invoke [modulo ? 2*reduce "+ ?] 100
```

(`invoke` calls the function, `pr` prints the result)

Explanation:

There is only one points need explaining: `reduce`. That is similar to `fold` in some other languages: `reduce "f [1 2 3 4]` calculate `(f (f (f 1 2) 3) 4)`. In this case, `reduce "+ ?` calculate total of elements of digits in `?`.

Numbers in LOGO is represented by word, so `reduce`, a library function can receive a word as its second parameter (while `apply` can't)

Answer (score 0):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 16 bytes

```
/o. &
\i@h /+.+F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/X09BjSsm0yFDQV9bT9vt/39LS2MzAA)

Prints twice the digit sum as the truthy result and `0` otherwise.

The code looks so painfully suboptimal with the two spaces and the repeated `.` and `+`, but I just can't figure out a more compact layout.

#### Explanation

```
/    Switch to Ordinal mode.
i    Read all input as a string.
.    Duplicate.
h    Split off the first character.
&    Fold the next command over the remaining characters (i.e. push each character
     in turn and then execute the command).
/    Switch back to Cardinal mode (not a command).
+    Add. This is folded over the characters, which implicitly converts them 
     to the integer value they represent and adds them to the leading digit.
.+   Duplicate and add, to double the digit sum.
F    Test for divisibility. Gives 0 if the input is not divisible by twice its
     digit sum and the (positive/truthy) divisor otherwise.
\    Switch to Ordinal mode.
o    Implicitly convert the result to a string and print it.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7, <s>197</s> <s>133</s> 126 bytes

<s>First try</s> Second try, fixed it, -9 characters on variable name, and changing it into function for the other subtraction with help of Olivier Grégoire

Changed boolean to int, now return 0 for true values, other number for falsy

```java
int b(String a){int t=0;for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){t+=Integer.parseInt(""+a.charAt(i));}return(Integer.parseInt(a)%(t*2));}
```

```java
boolean a(String a){int t=0;for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){t+=Integer.parseInt(""+a.charAt(i));}return(Integer.parseInt(a)%(t*2)==0);}
```

Ungolfed

```java
int b(String a){
int t=0;for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
t+=Integer.parseInt(""+a.charAt(i));
}
return(Integer.parseInt(a)%(t*2));}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the golfing part of codegolf! First you can get a [lot of tips from this thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) to help you getting started. So let's golf, shall we? You're not forced to write full programs: you can write only a function, or if you use Java 8+, a lambda. Make sure to give short variable names and remove all your unneeded spaces (`A {` can be written as `A{`; `String[] args` as  `String[]a`). You can return results instead of printing. The code doesn't pass the test cases of the challenge, fixing it would be 1st.

Comment: Hello, which test case didn't it pass? About only a function, I have read other post that says you have to create full executable program, this includes imports if you use them, correct me if I'm wrong, thank you :)

Comment: Ah, I forgot to multiply it *2 sorry

Comment: Fixed and changed to a function, thank you

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
%QyssM`
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25QyssM%60&input=80&debug=0) It returns 0 for truthy, a non null positive integer for falsy.

**Explanations**

```
       Q    # Implicit input Q
      `     # Convert the input to a string
    sM      # For each character in Q, convert to integer
   s        # Sum the resulting list
  y         # Multiply by two
%Q          # Perform the modulo with the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 53 bytes

```
a->{int i=0,c=a;for(;c>0;c/=10)i+=c%10*2;return a%i;}
```

> 0 true
>
> >0 false

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## R, 71 bytes

```
f=function(x)`if`(x%%(sum(floor(x/10^(0:(nchar(x)-1)))%%10)*2)==0,T,F)
```

Using `floor(x/10^(0:(nchar(x)-1)))%%10` saves the usual hassle of converting to character and back.

```
> f(1)
[1] FALSE
> f(12)
[1] TRUE
> f(123456789)
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

### R, 58 bytes

```
(a<-scan())%%(2*sum(strtoi(el(strsplit(paste(a),"")))))<1
```

`a <- scan()` stores user's input in variable `a`.

This variable is of type `numeric`. The `paste` function converts it into `character` for the `strsplit` function to separate its digits. `el` permits to use only the first element of the `list` created by `strsplit`.

The `strtoi` function converts then the digits back into `numeric`, for the function `sum` to, well, sum, before doubling the result.

To finish, divisibility of `a` with the double sum of its digits is tested by the `... %% ... < 1` part, outputing `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 26 bytes

```
000\~2*%n;
0(?\c%:{a*+}+i:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DAIKbOSEs1z5rLQMM@JlnVqjpRS7tWO9Pq/39zCwA)

Output is 0 for truthy, non-0 for falsey.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 72 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
For i=1To[Len(A1)]:s=s+Int(Mid([A1],i,1)):Next:s=s*2:?Int([A1]/s)=[A1]/s
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 29 bytes

Here goes my first "real" codegolf attempt...

```
_2:x;2:$'0 z;[(z~+z;]x~z~2*%`
```

Outputs "0" if true, anything else if false.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S81JzU3NK/n/P97IqsLayEpF3UChyjpao6pOu8o6tqKuqs5ISzXh/39DAwNDAA)

Explanation:

```
_             push input into main stack
2:            pop number and push it twice
x;            store one of them as x
2:            pop again and push twice 
$'            pop and get length, push it to control stack
0 z;          initiate accumulator "z" with value zero 
[             for length of input number (loop start), 
(             pop off first digit,
z~            retrieve "z",
+             add popped digit to it,
z;            store "z"  again 
]             (end of looped statement)
x~            retrieve "x" (copy of original number)
z~            retrieve "z" (accumulated digit sum)
2*            double accumulated digit sum
%             modulus the digit sum and original number
`             pop result to output.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, <strike>30</strike> 29 bytes

```
f(x)=x/2sum(digits(x)) in 0:x
```

saved a byte thanks to [caird-coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)

Comment: This seems to fail for 60: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/TaNC07ZC30iruDRXIyUzPbOkGCiiqZCZp2BgVfG/oCgzryQnTyNNw9DcSFOTC8E3M9DU/A8A "Julia 0.5 – Try It Online")

Comment: you're right, the problem was order of operations. fixed it by saving a byte, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 14 bytes

**Solution:**

```
(2*+/48!$x)!x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X8NIS1vfxEJRpUJTscLKzOD/fwA)

**Examples:**

```
  (2*+/48!$x)!x:18
0
  (2*+/48!$x)!x:123
3
  (2*+/48!$x)!x:390
6
```

**Explanation:**

Evaluation is performed right-to-left, unfortunately modulo is `b!a` rather than `a!b` hence the need for brackets. Returns `0` for truthy, positive integer for falsey per spec.

```
(2*+/48!$x)!x: / the solution
            x: / store input in variable x
           !   / modulo right by the left ( e.g. 3!10 => 1, aka 10 mod 3 ) 
(         )    / the left
        $x     / string ($) input, 123 => "123"
     48!       / modulo with 48, "123" => 1 2 3
   +/          / sum over, +/1 2 3 => 6
 2*            / double, 6 => 12
```

**Notes:**

- Prepend solution with `~` (not) to give a true/false result.

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, 36 Bytes

Unlike [the other ><> response](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/131734/76025), this takes the number itself as input as opposed to the digits. Of course, because of that it's a bit longer longer.

```
:&>:a%:}-\1-?\2*&$%n;
  \?)0:,a/l +<
```

#### Explanation:

```
:&
```

Duplicates input, stores a copy in the register.

```
  >:a%:}-\
  \?)0:,a/
```

Converts the number into its digits.

```
         \1-?\
         /l +<
```

Sum the digits

```
              2*&$%n;
```

Multiplies the digit sum by 2, and prints the original number modulo that sum. Output is, then, 0 for truthy and something else otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Deorst), 16 bytes

```
iE"E|miEH:+zE|%N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f8/01XJtSY309XDSrvKtUbV7////4bmRgA)

### How it works

Implicitly inputs and outputs, example: `172`

```
iE"              - To string;  STACK = ['172']
   E|            - Splat;      STACK = ['1' '7' '2']
     mi          - To integer; STACK = [1 7 2]
       EH        - Sum;        STACK = [10]
         :+      - Double;     STACK = [20]
           zE|   - Push input; STACK = [20 172]
              %N - Divides?    STACK = [0]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 33 bytes

```lua
nt(a%(sum(explode(""..a,"."))*2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z@vRCNRVaO4NFcjtaIgJz8lVUNJSU8vUUdJT0lTU8tIU/P///@GRgA)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 59 bytes

```clj
(fn[n](= 0(rem n(* 2(apply +(map #(-(int %)48)(str n)))))))
```

---

```clj
(defn sum-of-digits? [n]
  (let [ds (map #(- (int %) 48) (str n)) ; Stringify n, and parse each digit char of the string
        d-sum (* 2 (apply + ds))] ; Get the doubled sum
    (= 0 (rem n d-sum)))) ; Check if the remainder of (/ n sum) is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>54</del> 32 bytes

Saved 22 bytes thanks to the comment of @user

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwEEX3/YohICQIpVXRWmhBEMGFK3VVReKjNVKnkkRBpN9eI7pRZ3ZzuHPmmp0sZVNtT4edhZlUCA/vJkvIY5hbrbCAJIUpWkgaTFL0beWWFsc2xqtA8I0vzVgVyrY3ogHYH3I4OwmXujAxjLSW9@ztWYsYlqicyH0ANxdHbYmcZQt9tcf7mokvnnMWBUz8wTCgaJ@MRhTsvOBPhYksDdWgRwhIaZ@AnZCAA/I8JOuHlKA7/GRrr/aaJw)

```scala
n=>n.toInt%(n+n:\0)(_.asDigit+_)
```

Comment: You should be able to use a lambda here. Also, `n.concat(n)` can be replaced with `(n+n)`. Lastly, folding is shorter than map+sum. 32 bytes: [`n=>n.toInt%(n+n:\0)(_.asDigit+_)`](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwEEX3/YohICQIpVXRWmhBEMGFK3VVReKjNVKnkkRBpN9eI7pRZ3ZzuHPmmp0sZVNtT4edhZlUCA/vJkvIY5hbrbCAJIUpWkgaTFL0beWWFsc2xqtA8I0vzVgVyrY3ogHYH3I4OwmXujAxjLSW9@ztWYsYlqicyH0ANxdHbYmcZQt9tcf7mokvnnMWBUz8wTCgaJ@MRhTsvOBPhYksDdWgRwhIaZ@AnZCAA/I8JOuHlKA7/GRrr/aaJw)