# Is it a pure word?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

## Introduction

A pure word (or perfect word), as defined by me, is a word where the sum of the position in the alphabet of each letter in the word is perfectly divisible by the total length of the word. For example, `abcb` is a perfect word because `1 + 2 + 3 + 2 = 8`, and `8 / 4 = 2`.

## Your task

Given a word as input, output whether or not it is a perfect word. The word may always be assumed to be lowercase.

### Scoring

This is code-golf, so shortest program in bytes wins.

### Examples

```
abcb: truthy
ccc: truthy
aaa: truthy
pure: truthy
word: truthy
bed: falsy
code: falsy
bode: falsy
```

Comment: What type of outputs are allowed? For example, `0` for truthy and a non-consistent nonzero number for falsy? Any two values? Truthy and falsy swapped? @All: you may want to vote [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19202/36398)

Comment: @LuisMendo check the [related meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey)

Comment: I know what "truthy" and "falsy" mean. I'm asking if the outputs can be non-consistent values (i.e. more than two values), or for example two distinct truthy values. You need to specify the output options allowed by the challenge. Voting to close as unclear until resolved

Comment: I'm pretty sure our consensus is that there is no default for decision problem output. E.g., is `false` for a perfect number and `true` for a non-perfect one allowed? What about `1` for a perfect number and any other number otherwise, or positive for perfect and negative for non-perfect?

Comment: @taRadvylfsriksushilani The consensus [appears not to be](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19202/default-policy-for-ouput-in-decision-problems).  However I would really like it if something as basic as output specifications were put in the challenge itself instead of hidden away somewhere on meta.  It's not very beginner friendly seeing as experienced users don't seem to always recall the exact state of the meta.

Comment: you may be interested to know that "word" itself is a perfect word, as is "pure". "perfect" itself is not one, so perhaps they should be known as pure words?

Comment: @Rugnir this is interesting. I'll rename the question

Answer (score 19):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>37</s> 16 bytes

```
[ mean fixnum? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDgIhEEV7TjHhAFtaaGFpbGyMlbEYZmeVCAOB2cT18gg27@W//AVJU2m36/ly2kNEfU1VUX1VTxXeXITDP0MurLrl4kXhycIFg//2Z5IKB2MsOnLWWCLqRMROx/MoaeYxhtodIqPA4j@yxiM82g4Ecw4bTBUoMJb2Aw)

Is the mean of the input an integer?

##### Why does this work?

Four reasons.

- Strings in Factor are just sequences of code points.
- Because the question is asking for a sum divided by a length. Otherwise known as the mean.
- The `mean` word returns a ratio, not a float. In Factor, ratios automatically reduce to simplified form, which can be an integer. We can check for divisibility after taking the mean by checking whether the result is an integer or a ratio.
- It doesn't matter whether the input ranges from 1-26 or 97-122. It doesn't change whether the mean is an integer or not.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3), 33 bytes

```
lambda s:sum(map(ord,s))%len(s)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcg7CsMwEEXR3qt4TdAMuAnpTLySkGL0IwJrJCSnyOoV5Opwb/2dn6KPMeJ@SLZe0Lf@zZSlUml@7cy3Iyh1ft6HYsfLiHXWrDDOuYmITGzw1yw@XDl9L7E0JCSFbgtQW9KTIiXm8Qc)

Comment: wow i feel dumb now after reading this

Answer (score 12):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>42</s> <s>39</s> 33 bytes

```r
function(w)!mean(utf8ToInt(w))%%1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NcUzE3NTFPo7QkzSIk3zOvBCiiqapq@D9NQykxKTlJSZNTWSGEC8hLTk5GcBITExGcpNQUMMcNrCw/JRXBS4Lz/gMA)

-6 bytes thanks to m90.

Comment: I think it's generally accepted to take string input as a vector of char codes.

Comment: @pajonk ehh, that's always been a bit of a gray area to me, R has a perfectly good string type so I prefer to take input that way.

Comment: Ok, I respect that. Also, the [default for decision-problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/decision-problem/info) is that truthy/falsy may be swapped for -1 (but that also feels like a design choice more than golf).

Comment: Improvement: change `sum` to `mean` and the modulus to 1.

Comment: use the new syntax: \\(w)!mean(utf8ToInt(w))%%1

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
OIgÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f3zP98LT//6MtzXUULC2A2BJExwIA) Takes input as a list of codepoints.

Comment: It would be more impressive to 'tie' Jelly, Husk and Vyxal-K if the input format was the same: each of those others takes a string as input, rather than already converted to a list of codepoints.  Note that hyper-neutrino's Jelly answer would only be 3 bytes ([SọL](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJT4buNTCIsIiIsIiIsWyJbOTcsOTgsOTksOThdIl1d)) if the input was already converted to codepoints...

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 5 bytes

```
OSḍ@L
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJPU+G4jUBMIiwiw4figqwiLCIiLFsiW1wiYWJjYlwiLCBcImNjY1wiLCBcImFhYVwiLCBcImJlZFwiLCBcImNvZGVcIiwgXCJib2RlXCJdIl1d)

```
OSḍ@L    Main Link
O        ord (vectorizes)
 S       sum
  ḍ@     is this divisible by
    L    the length of the input?
```

If outputting inconsistent truthy/falsy values is allowed:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 4 bytes

```
OSọL
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJPU+G7jUwiLCLDh+KCrCIsIiIsWyJbXCJhYmNiXCIsIFwiY2NjXCIsIFwiYWFhXCIsIFwiYmVkXCIsIFwiY29kZVwiLCBcImJvZGVcIl0iXV0=)

```
OSọL    Main Link
O       ord (vectorizes)
 S      sum
  ọ     how many times is this divisible by
   L    the length?
```

This works using an observation made by [caird coinheringaahing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60084609) in chat that you do not need to account for the offset between A = 1 and A = 65 when you take the codepoint, since the codepoint offset will be added `len(X)` times and not affect the modulo.

Yes, caird also just straight up gave the algorithm, but to be fair, the observation was the only non-trivial part about this solution anyway.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 58 bytes

```
w=>!([...w].reduce((s,c)=>s+parseInt(c,36)-10,0)%w.length)
```

Comment: Doesn't `!` have higher precedence than `%`?

Comment: @Neil Oh yeah...I added the `!` last minute and didn't really think it through.

Comment: 50 bytes: `s=>[...s].map(_=>x+=s.charCodeAt(i++),x=i=0)|x%i<1`. Using `map` is kind of wasteful here, it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: -10 is not necessary

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
C∑$LḊ
```

[Try It Online!](https://vyxapedia.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCJD4oiRJEzhuIoiLCIiLCIiLCJhYmNiIl0=)

Same thing as my Jelly solution.

```
C∑$LḊ    Full Program
C        ord (vectorizes)
 ∑       sum
  $      swap; bring the string back to the top
   L     length
    Ḋ    is the ord sum divisible by the length?
```

Answer (score 7):

## Excel, <s>59</s> 54 bytes

<sup>Saved 5 bytes thanks to pajonk.</sup>

```
=MOD(SUM(CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1))),LEN(A1))=0
```

Input is in cell `A1`. Output is wherever the formula is.

- `SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))` creates an array with values 1 to the word length.
- `MID(A1,SEQUENCE(~),1)` pulls out each letter from the input one at a time.
- `CODE(MID(~))` finds the ASCII code for each letter. We don't have to convert this to 1-26 because it's 1 extra 96 for ever letter of the input so divisibility will be the same.
- `SUM(CODE(~))` adds all those values.
- `MOD(SUM(~),LEN(A1))` returns 0 if it's a whole number and a decimal if it isn't. If anything, this is the opposite of what we want because `0` is falsey and other numbers are truthy, at least in Excel.
- `MOD(~)=0` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

[image: Result]

---

I found an alternative with the same byte count. It works in reverse and exploits the fact that `CODE()` only pulls the left-most character if it's given a string of greater length. I almost like it more, though, because it has 5 closing parentheses in a row.

```
=MOD(SUM(CODE(RIGHT(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1))))),LEN(A1))=0
```

Comment: I think you may omit the `-96` as it's repeated `LEN(A1)` times in the sum and doesn't affect divisibility. Also, I don't have excel near me to check, but shouldn't simply passing `LEN(A1)` to the second argument of `MOD` work?

Comment: @pajonk Spot on. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
f w=sum(fromEnum<$>w)`mod`length w<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYs9D8IgFAB3fsUbHNqkHdxpN50c3YyxD3i0RD4M0PDzsV2q211yt2B6k7W1aihDWl2jY3AXvzp@Gks7uaAmS37OCxR@rg6NH1Rg8DDdqwtP3pcQVdramfLNeGLwicbnxnQaTMtgHyoKKaAf4R5XYlLKgxHxYEFq5yvatEVB0c/Ev30B)

Answer (score 7):

## [Vyxal 2.4.1](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `K`, <s>4</s> 3 bytes

```
ṁ1Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=%E1%B9%811%E1%B8%8A&inputs=pure&header=&footer=)

Ah yes classic pre-2.6 jank ftw. *-1 thanks to Dominic*

### Explained

```
ṁ1Ḋ
      # First, the input is converted to a list of corresponding ordinal values by the `K`(eg mode) flag:
ṁ     #   push the arithmetic mean of that list
 1Ḋ   #   is that divisible by 1? (i.e is it a whole number)
```

Comment: [3 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=K&code=%E1%B9%811%E1%B8%8A&inputs=pure&header=&footer=)?

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 24 bytes

```
lambda s:sum(s)%len(s)<1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY7chJzk1ISFYqtiktzNYo1VXNS84CUjSFE-mZGQVFmXolGmkaSUmJScpKSpiYXQiQ5ORlVIDExEVUgKTUFTUt-SiqaEogIxL4FCyA0AA)

Takes input as a byte string. We don't need to subtract `95` from each element, because the sum will end up having `95 * length` added on, which has no effect on the result modulo `length`.

Comment: best python code pxeger!

Answer (score 7):

## Java, 31 bytes

```java
s->s.chars().sum()%s.length()<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdG9agMxDADgOfcUJhCwCzF0zs8bFAoZSwZZ9l188dmHJSeUkme/OrRday1C0ic0aIQbbEd7Xfw0p8xirLUu7IPuS0T2KeqXXTcXEzwKDEAk3sBH8dWJGr99YuCabslbMdWpPHH2cfg4C8gDqYpX79lZj8Bu/zM7iv6w0PZIGi@QSSpNZZJqQzq4OPBFqv3rsutWp09iN@lUWM91j0OUvWZHLNdg0KyV@h8hYtMAQNPMJbsmuqdsm8i4tsFk29fMH3p@4tE9lm8)

Answer (score 7):

## [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck), 162 bytes

```
>+[+[>+<+<]>]+[,[>[>+<<->-]<[>>>+<<<-]>>>>+<<[<+>-]<<+>>]<<]>>>[-]>>[<+>-]<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>[-]+++++++>[-]<[>+++++++<-]>>[<.[-]>[-]>[-]]<[-.[-]]
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##LYxdCgMxCITfexVrTyBzEfFhf1pYFtolEPb41iERojOj@da2HN9P385MiItDTCwQ4k8HnSk0zAFq08BQbsK8Oqozde5m7Iqa9b22KKpWHBi3rOC1jKIs/nQ2KC/S5iOOPh6ZV2/v@9f2Pw)

outputs `0` for **truthy** and `1` for **falsey**

This one was a lot of fun. Not necessary golf-optimal but hey, brainfuck solution :)

### Explanation

```
; 96 algorithm from esolangs constants
; initialise tape to (1)/96/0/0/0
>+[+[>+<+<]>]+[
    ; while(getchar())
    ,[>
        [>+<<->-]
        <[>>>+<<<-]>>>>+<<[<+>-]<<+>>
        ; 0/96/(0)/cumulative/length
    ]
    <<
]

; divmod algorithm from esolangs
>>>[-]>>[<+>-]
<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]

; prepare 0 for output
>[-]+++++++>[-]<[>+++++++<-]

; if(sum%length){print 1}else{print 0}
>>[<.[-]>[-]>[-]]<[-.[-]]
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 25 bytes

```julia
!x=sum(Int,x)%length(x)<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpLCsIwFIXheVdxWxASyKTTYJy7Crl51EbibckD0tXHFrGe0Qf/eZXgcayt9VWl8mZ3yqLyS3D0zDOr/Dq2aYkQPDnwBNGhPZwY72AfCniAgrQGn9kRBAxy@LY1esqBGIK6QY@8c2QbaqMl5FjyvHXGmNOIeFo7K2HCkPbLYt3P@u8P)

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(Buffer(s).join`+`)%s.length<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc/LCsIwEIXhvU8RCkKCNMW9deGTdDKd9ELISCYt@PRRBF1Uxf0H/zkzrCCYpmuuI/dUfFukPdMKQV8W7ylpMXbmKXaHzuzFBopDHk/HghyFA9nAg/a6AoeuMkapplE5LXm87TYCEZ/gtwCAP8JR/xYegnxGHh9eM74CtwXlDg)

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>34</s> 24 bytes

```
1∣Mean@LetterNumber@#&
```

-10 bytes from @att

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73/BRx2Lf1MQ8B5/UkpLUIr/S3KTUIgdltf8BRZl5JdHKunZpDs4ZiUWJyUDZYgflWLW64OTEvLpqLqXEpOQkJR0upeTkZBCVmJgIogpKi1JBdHl@UQqITkoFU8n5KWDhJCidqMRV@x8A)

Comment: This isn't reusable, since `z` will already be defined on subsequent calls. Input also needs to be taken as a list of characters in order to correctly handle length-1 strings (Mathematica treats them as characters). [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73/BRx2Lf1MQ8B5/UkpLUIr/S3KTUIgdltf8BRZl5JdHKunZpDs4ZiUWJyUDZYgflWLW64OTEvLpqLqXEpOQkJR0upeTkZBCVmJgIogpKi1JBdHl@UQqITkoFU8n5KWDhJCidqMRV@x8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 17 bytes

```scala
s=>s.sum%s.size<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BisJADIbvPsVPcaEFFfYqtqBPIHjwnJlJtVI7dTKKbOmzd4O6hdVLEr7kg/xiqabBmxPbiC2HUvveBwe@R26cYN226CaA4xKVvC6W2MVQNQfkBTbe10wN8kHyQhZyPX9prX549T2ot@NLqg1IyFiTYF4ghivPnsxa@46I6B0Zdg9UUi2j6R1/QPMPKssWpQ9M9ogOloSRykyjtZqBXabvP7xWs8S6SSWZCg7VjWWJaTemTSXrR0k3f2OSqd1P@uEX)

Answer (score 5):

## APL+WIN, <s>22</s> 16 bytes

Prompts for string

```
0=(⍴s)|+/⎕av⍳s←⎕
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv4GtxqPeLcWaNdr6QJnEske9m4uBskD2f6A81/80LvXEpOQkdS4gIzk5GUwnJiaC6aTUFIh4fkoqRADEAAA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of characters. The `c` can be removed by instead taking input as an array of codepoints.

```
xc vUl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cQ&code=eGMgdlVs&input=ImFiY2Ii)

```
xc vUl     :Implicit input of array U
x          :Sum of
 c         :  Codepoints
   v       :Is divisible by
    Ul     :  Length of U
```

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
0=#|1#.96|3&u:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DWyVawyV9SzNaozVSq3@a3JxpSZn5CsYKtgqpCmoJyYlJ6mjiCQnJ6MKJCYmQgUMIAJJqSmoAsn5KaloSkAi/wE)

*-1 thanks to south*

Comment: Little late but here's 14, `0=#|1#.96|3&u:`.

Comment: Never too late, thanks

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Razetime*

```
¦L¹Σ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@hZT6Hdp5b/P///2ilxKTkJCUdpeTkZCCZmJgIJJNSU0Ai@SmpIA6IigUA)

Outputs truthy (non-zero) for perfect words, falsy (zero) for non-perfect words.

Comment: sum works on strings: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@hZT6Hdp5b/P///2ilxKTkJCUdpeTkZCCZmJgIJJNSU0Ai@SmpIA6IigUA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: @Razetime - Aha!  Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 5):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> <s>9</s> 8 bytes

*Edit: -3 bytes thanks to ovs, and -1 byte thanks to DLosc*

```
≠|·+´@-⊢
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4omgfMK3K8K0QC3iiqIKCkbCqCDin6gicHVyZSIsIndvcmQiLCJhYmNkIuKfqQ==)

Outputs nonzero (truthy) for non-perfect words, zero (falsy) for perfect words.

Comment: You can use `@` instead of `'a'` and the `¨` is not necessary.

Comment: @ovs - Thanks a lot!  And: I must be slowly starting to understnad BQN, because I *think* I could actually understand both of those golfs right away...

Comment: Turns out the `˜` is not necessary either: without it, the sum-and-mod is applied to a bunch of negative numbers instead of positive numbers, which produces the same results vis-a-vis zero vs non-zero.

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-nl`, 17 bytes

```ruby
p$_.sum%$_.size<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcUxCoAwDAXQ/Z9DRwV37yJJmqFgm9JaRA9v1OW92vlyL8M2t57Gv3jrurgTC0NEQEQovSpOqwGsAWJBwR@PlSNabj7l/QU)

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AlXq@4NFe1Tl9F38bw///EpOQkruTkZK7ExESugtKiVK7y/KIUrqTUFK7k/JRUriQg8S@/oCQzP6/4v25eDgA) making use of `$_`

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṁ`, <strike>11</strike> 10  bytes

-1 thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)

```
ƛkanḟ;∑?LḊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuYAiLCIiLCLGm2thbuG4nzviiJE/TOG4iiIsIiIsImFiY2IiXQ==)

## Explanation

```
ƛkanḟ;∑?LḊ
ƛ            Start a mapping lambda for input
 ka          Lowercase alphabet
   n         Current letter
    ḟ        Find letter in the alphabet, return index
     ;       Close mapping lambda
      ∑      Sum the list of indices.
       ?L    Get Length of input
         Ḋ   Check if Sum is divisible by the length.
```

Comment: probably can be golfed a lot

Comment: You don't need to increment because all that does is increase the sum by the length, which doesn't change its divisibility.

Answer (score 4):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>103</s> 98 bytes

```
	L =SIZE(W =INPUT)
N	W LEN(1) . X REM . W :F(O)
	S =S + ORD(X)	:(N)
O	OUTPUT =1	EQ(REMDR(S,L))
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcsxC8IwEIbh@fIrvvEORSg4FbLlhEK8aNKS4ljsJnbw/xMzvcv7/L7HdnyurVGEL9NLucJP9lhmcUYVUY0HwQUrst57K8YbJ3FU@o8TUg68Co1s4hKlZe4UfiB9cgchczlHEacWWtv29x8)

Prints `1` for truthy and nothing for falsey.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
¬﹪ΣＥθ℅ιＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBDYAgDADAVXi2CU7gCqImTtCAkSaVCgHXr97vYqYWlcRsb1w6rNohaBqicIwbAj1Qvdta4kICjIjeLWe5eob6B2ezcrLY9MoH) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` for a perfect word, nothing if not. Explanation:

```
    θ        Input string
   Ｅ         Map over characters
      ι      Current character
     ℅       Ordinal
  Σ          Sum
¬﹪           Is divisible by
        θ    Input string
       Ｌ     Length
             Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
s=input();print(sum(ord(c)-95for c in s)%len(s)<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2M6@gtERD07qgKDOvRKO4NFcjvyhFI1lT19I0Lb9IIVkhM0@hWFM1JzVPo1jTxlDz/38A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 8 bytes

```
iys&+l%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zslhNO0dV8f//xKTkJAA)

```
i         - read STDIN onto stack as codepoints
 ys       - push length of the stack, save to backup cell
   &+     - sum the codepoints on the stack (1)
     l    - load the number of chars from the backup cell
      %   - module math to push "0" if evenly divisble, ">0" otherwise
       !  - negate modulo result so that 0->1 and other->0
```

(1) The code includes the length of the original stack in the sum of the codepoints to save the `p` byte that would be needed to delete it.  But it doesn't change the result of the modulo math to get the final result.

When the code exits, the only thing on the stack is the `0|1` result, which is printed as a number automatically.

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 46 bytes

```
.
$&26$*
+T`1l`_3l`\D.
^
2
O^`.
3
1
^(1+)2\1*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcRBCoAgEAXQ/T@HhRUIGnSCoGWblmIzTi4EMYjub73Fe9KbK7dOb9QMVO8WNWI6yBY650J@NQhw2AMZzLAI2k6D83ZUrdWUCzhKhIiAmRHTBbmvhPj3AQ) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.
$&26$*
```

Append 26 `1`s to each letter.

```
+T`1l`_3l`\D.
```

Cycle the letters through the alphabet, removing a `1` each time. Once the letter reaches `a`, replace it with a `3`. (Note that this numbers the alphabet in reverse but this doesn't affect the divisibility check.)

```
^
2
O^`.
```

Insert a `2` and then sort the digits in reverse order, so you have the `3`s for each letter, the `2`, and then the `1`s representing the sum of the positions.

```
3
1
```

Change the `3`s into `1`s.

```
^(1+)2\1*$
```

Check that the leading `1`s divide the trailing `1`s.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>14</s> 11 bytes

-3 bytes from @Dominic van Essen's improvement

```
{~(#x)!+/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k/#eJxFztEKwiAUxvF7n8JWFxux3KKL0EeJoKPTNrZm6YkcUc+eI6y7H5wPzt/w5ztfhmKxZuFFCPLn6jC9HTeU0iBOthf5yUA3iCAm4YrjvDlkIJXMRH2crZRKBIBEqZtMVN+BbXSyTCaMtIhXzxmb72c7mI1HUL0OqoXxrDfKXtjtrj12dvRsu6urfcU6X3ZYQnnVzmiF5cO6hsw1nKK7YzuRmPNz7Pk5BnFqYPBxEh8my78/fUBWfw==)

- `+/x` take the sum of the ASCII codes of the (strictly lowercase) input
- `(#x)!` mod this sum by the length of the input
- `~` "not" the result, i.e. return `1` if the sum is evenly divisible by the length (i.e. the mod returns 0), and `0` otherwise

Comment: Can you leave-out the ```48!``` for [11 bytes](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxFztEKwiAUxvF7n8JWFxux3KKL0EeJoKPTNrZm6YkcUc+eI6y7H5wPzt/w5ztfhmKxZuFFCPLn6jC9HTeU0iBOthf5yUA3iCAm4YrjvDlkIJXMRH2crZRKBIBEqZtMVN+BbXSyTCaMtIhXzxmb72c7mI1HUL0OqoXxrDfKXtjtrj12dvRsu6urfcU6X3ZYQnnVzmiF5cO6hsw1nKK7YzuRmPNz7Pk5BnFqYPBxEh8my78/fUBWfw==)...?

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```sh
a=(+\#\#${(s::)^1})
(((a)%$#1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZBCoQwDAXQ/T9FoBUSZuVWkLmICGna4q5DZSgonr3SzeNd59EzC3dd@bO5zfmbz2WRfX4EzKwyeTeLdAFyqdSIocECzAyqit@/JrRSI0KKsBITwkBuQibfkOwo5L@jT38B)

In Zsh, `##x` in arithmetic mode returns the codepoint of `'x'`.

```sh
        ${(s::) 1}    # split $1 into characters
   +\#\#${(s::)^1}    # append `+##` to each element
a=(+\#\#${(s::)^1})   # save as $a
(((a)%$#1))           # join $a on spaces, evaluate (+##a +##b ...) % $#1
                      # arithmetically
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 125 bytes

Wow I feel like an idiot after reading all these other amazing answers.

```
j=[ord(k)-96 for k in str(input(""))]
l=len(j)
while len(j)>1:j[0]+=j[1];del j[1]
print("%sy"%("truth"if j[0]%l<1else"fals"))
```

I think how this works is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
!%sCMQl
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=%21%25sCMQl&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abcb%22%0A%22ccc%22%0A%22aaa%22%0A%22pure%22%0A%22word%22%0A%22bed%22%0A%22code%22%0A%22bode%22&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
!%sCMQl  | Full code
!%sCMQlQ | with implicit variables filled
---------+-------------------------------------------------------
   CMQ   | Replace each character in the input with its codepoint
  s      | Sum the resulting list
 %    lQ | Mod the sum with the length of the input
!        | Boolean negate (i.e. 0 -> True, other -> False)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
$Σ\£÷
```

Input as a list of characters. Could be 1 byte less by taking the input as a list of codepoints.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/l3OKYQ4sPb///P1opUUlHKQmIk8F0LFc0mAXBIB5IHoJBvAIgqxSIi4A4FSxSDmTlQ0VSwCJJYDkYLxkqnwLXkYQqAgA)

**Explanation:**

```python
$     # Map each character in the (implicit) input-list to a codepoint integer
 Σ    # Sum this list
  \   # Swap so the (implicit) input-list is at the top again
   £  # Pop and push its length
    ÷ # Check if the earlier sum is divisible by this length
      # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 113 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate][S N
S _Duplicate][T N
T   S _Read_STDIN_as_char][T    T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
S _Duplicate][S S S T   S T S N
_Push_10][T S S T   _Subtract][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_PRINT_RESULT][T S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_PRINT_RESULT][S N
N
_Discard_top][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    S T T   _Modulo][N
T   S T N
_If_0_Jump_to_Label_TRUTHY][S S T   T   N
_Push_-1][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_TRUTHY][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][T   N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Since Whitespace can only read input one character at a time, the input must contain a trailing newline so we'll know when we're done reading characters.
Whitespace also lacks truthy/falsey values, so this program will output `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey (could be 28 bytes less with `0` as truthy and a positive integer as falsey).

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##VYxRCoAwDEO/k1PkatsY6N9AwePXdDpBWsJLaHpt@9mPUVqPkETPT0AIQBrJKPsZTngVi10inzdeZDX7jgyp/K6NiCi1Vd4) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Integer length = 0
Integer sum = 0
Start LOOP:
  Integer input = STDIN as character
  If(input == '\n'):
    Jump to PRINT_RESULT
  sum = sum + input
  length = length + 1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

PRINT_RESULT:
  Integer result = 0
  Integer mod = sum modulo length
  If(mod == 0):
    Skip to TRUTHY
  Else:
    result = -1
  TRUTHY:
  result = result + 1
  Print result as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 49 bytes

```c
i,l;f(*a){for(i=l=0;*a;i+=*a++)l++;return!(i%l);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCsIwEEDRfU8RI4VMU8G1oTfwCG4mk0QGYippiovSs0cRhSwf/9OJIqZ7rTxGE9SAsIU5K57idDYDGtbTgFpD1NpkX9acDor7CGavR@cDJy@KX4pCEM/MqQQl@7hcRO9uSY4CRxE@DboHclKwdd/5KtGSlWD@JKJGzzX7hq85u4bWt6LZta/9ca9v)

Takes input as a wide string; returns `1` for pure words and `0` for others.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
{(#x)!+/x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rWUK7QVNTWr6jl4kqLVkpMSk5SigWxkpOTIYzExEQIo6C0KBXCKs8vSoGwklKhjOT8FKhkEpgFAJzoGo4=)

*Saves a byte by not using the Not operator (~)*

Quick and simple. Return `0` for true and any other value for false.

Explanation:

```
{(#x)!+/x}    Main function. Takes x as input
      +/x     Sum of all charcodes in x
     !        Modulo
 (#x)         Length of x
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$4\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 3.292 bytes

```
%LxS
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyIlTHhTIiwiY29kZSJd)

Port of K answer. Prints 0 for truthy and a positive number for falsey.

```
%LxS
   S # Sum of charcodes
%    # Modulo
 Lx  # Length of input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>26</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
l&v
v+>l1-?!
>&%n
```

[Try it](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoibCZ2XG52Kz5sMS0/IVxuPiYlbiIsImlucHV0IjoiIiwic3RhY2siOiJiZWQiLCJzdGFja19mb3JtYXQiOiJjaGFycyIsImlucHV0X2Zvcm1hdCI6ImNoYXJzIn0=)

Exits with error, which is allowed by default.

This is my first answer in this language, so it can probably be golfed.

Input is assumed to be on the stack. Output is any non-zero number for falsy, `0` for truthy.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 41 bytes

```
$=>[=floor<=average map&=>[to :integer&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?CEzrEg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle), 28 bytes

```
'0|2_~<.+!>S/>i,..<.@2\)/(%S
```

Prints "0" if the word is pure.

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=pure#%270%7C2_%7E%3C.%2B!%3ES%2F%3Ei%2C..%3C.%402%5C)%2F(%25S)!

Roughly equivalent to this C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int total = 0, len = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        total += c;
        ++len;
    }
    if (total % len == 0) puts("0");
}
```

The code unfolds to this triangle:

```
      '
     0 |
    2 _ ~
   < . + !
  > S / > i
 , . . < . @
2 \ ) / ( % S
```

[image]

Control flow starts at the north corner heading southwest, on the red path:

- `'0`: push a zero to the stack
- `2`: duplicate the top of the stack, so it now contains two zeroes
- `<`: redirect control flow
- `i`: read a single character in and push it to the stack
- `>`: branch

If EOF was read, control flow continues on the blue path; otherwise, control flow continues on the green path.

The green path performs the necessary additions before looping:

- `+`: add the top two values on the stack
- `_`: redirect control flow
- `.`: no-op
- `S`: swap the top two values in the stack
- `.`: no-op
- `\`: redirect control flow
- `)`: increment the top of the stack
- `/`: redirect control flow
- `.`: no-op again
- `S`: swap the values back
- `<`: redirect control flow, merging with the red path

On the blue path (after EOF is read), the following instructions are seen:

- `<`: redirect control flow
- `..`: more no-ops
- `,`: pop the EOF off the stack
- `S`: swap the two values on the top of the stack
- `%`: pop two values off the stack and push `a % b`
- `(`: decrement the top of the stack
- `/`: redirect control flow
- `2`: duplicate the top of the stack
- `.`: another no-op
- `/`: redirect control flow
- `S`: "swap" the two values in the stack (effectively a no-op, since they're the same value)
- `>`: branch

If the word is pure, the stack contains two -1's, and the interpreter takes the magenta path. If the word is not pure, the stack contains two copies of some non-negative number, and the interpreter takes the yellow path.

On the magenta path, it prints a 0 before exiting:

- `,`: pop a value off the top of the stack
- `2`: duplicate the top of the stack (not necessary on this code path, but harmless)
- `|`: redirect control flow
- `~`: bitwise complement, changes -1 to 0
- `!`: print the top of the stack as a decimal integer
- `i`: attempt to read more input (always sees EOF)
- `@`: end program

The yellow path has a rather convoluted no-op before it exits:

- `\`: no-op when traversed in this direction
- `,`: pop from the stack
- `2`: duplicate the value on the stack (cancels out the `,`)
- `S`: "swap" the two identical values
- `@`: end program.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda s:(sum(ord(c)-95for c in s)/len(s)).is_integer()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc3BCsIwDMbxu09RdkoO6mF4UPBNBEnTVAtbW9IN8enrYCDklv8PPlK/y7vkscf7o080@0Cu3aCtMxQNwHi8XmJRxy5l1/A8SYaGeErtmfIiL1HAXnW7IcJAnv2AePgDM5smItN1VTHw2b4a8GKbS7ALv0P/AQ)

Comment: By the looks of it the code divides by 2. Shouldn't it divide by `len(s)`, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @dingledooper woops, will fix

Comment: You can get 53 bytes with the walrus operator `lambda s:int(b:=(sum(ord(c)-95for c in s)/len(s)))==b` (though tio.run doesn't recognize it)

Answer (score 2):

## [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/), <strike>101</strike> 83 bytes

```
bool P(string w){int i=0;foreach(var c in w){i+=(int)c%32;};return i%w.Length==0;};
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TVCxasMwEJ2tr7glIBNqQjuqHkqGLikEOnQIGeTz1TlwpSLJMcX426@KY0o1vEP33ju9E8YH9IFEhsiug/efmOjLqP@3au/7njCxd7F6JUeB0aiYbGIE7G2M8KImUJDPAit19dzCm2WnYwp53OkMNnSxXDSTKhrveziuJIzlxC4B1zvzmQNZvOirDYDAbuG2tc58iZunRzObQGkIDngzVgdyXbrU2TcbUIUqsh30Mgtq2JlcnpeHV2VubLf3EGuQW9nn5XxP1UfgRAd2pI/6ZjrxuSzNn3pWd5xFxDbYCCKKtVa@h/yJow@tNNQK@pakyfAL)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/173/66833) page for ways you can golf your program. We allow anonymous functions here, so you should be able to remove the `static Func<string,bool> P =`, as well as the spaces around the `=` and `=>`

Comment: @caird thanks for the welcome and the tips, that helped knock a significant chunk off

Comment: Suggest `return i%w.Length<1` instead of `return i%w.Length==0` and removing the innermost curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 85 bytes

```
fun i(s:String):Int{var a=0;for(i in s)a+=i.code-96;return if(a%s.length==0)1 else 0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdDBCsIwDAbgu08RBsKKOLaL4EYfwLO@QNplszhbSVs9jD37nOhF0C2HnL7kD7m40Bk7jk20YFJfHgMb24ryYEN/RwaUedU4Tg0YC17gRppMu5q2@13FFCJPY02Ka591ZNtwljIXBVDnCfLhvfaKxqaih6lWr4beE4cTR4J@ykxQaZUIkBIKgOEn0VonME8QcYncItNC0MNxvUAU1Z@g/O@504OSeaK@yfAE)

#### Ungolfed version:

```kotlin
fun isPure(s: String) : Int
{
    var acc = 0
    for(i in s) acc+= i.code-96
    return if(acc%s.length==0) 1 else 0
}
```

1 stands for Truthy and 0 stands for falsy, derived from this post [Interpretation of Truthy/Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
C₆%₌∑LḊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJgYWJjYjogdHJ1dGh5XG5jY2M6IHRydXRoeVxuYWFhOiB0cnV0aHlcbnB1cmU6IHRydXRoeVxud29yZDogdHJ1dGh5XG5iZWQ6IGZhbHN5XG5jb2RlOiBmYWxzeVxuYm9kZTogZmFsc3lgXG5cbuKGtVxcOi92aFxuXG7GmyIsIkPigoYl4oKM4oiRTOG4iiIsIm4kXCJgJSAtPiAlYCQlO1xcXG5qIiwiIl0=)

Comment: Nice! You don't need the space.

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJgYWJjYjogdHJ1dGh5XG5jY2M6IHRydXRoeVxuYWFhOiB0cnV0aHlcbnB1cmU6IHRydXRoeVxud29yZDogdHJ1dGh5XG5iZWQ6IGZhbHN5XG5jb2RlOiBmYWxzeVxuYm9kZTogZmFsc3lgXG5cbuKGtVxcOi92aFxuXG7GmyIsIkPigoYl4oKM4oiRTOG4iiIsIm4kXCJgJSAtPiAlYCQlO1xcXG5qIiwiIl0=) for 7 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](http://nim-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```
import sequtils,sugar
t=>t.foldl(a+b.int,0)%%t.len<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsMgEEDRfU4xBAJKg7Tb0PQu48SkgnFSHWlvb2lXZvcf/Oj3eiQmyGqd4F/qM0GW5OOmJ7DMQcPcATh6MqzQoyXbNyailojY8ijJtX5zWlpbdyLxctrtz9XvByeB7F5FfMhjLhumLiuZH2JWDktQeLHGRxmvehjEBBfvN13rFw)

Answer (score 2):

## D, 67 bytes

```
import std;int p(string w){return !(w.fold!"a+=b-96"(0)%w.length);}
```

ungolfed

```
import std;
int p(string w) {
    return !(w.fold!"a+=b-96"(0)%w.length);
}
// not much more readable, lol
```

takes a string `w`, and then performs a fold on it. The fold adds each char, minus 96, to the accumulator. 96 being the ascii value of the backtick character, one behind `a` (since this challenge specifies that the characters are 1-indexed). this effectively adds up all characters in the string. Then we perform a modulo for a divisibility check, and since we want 0 to be the true case, we invert it. Note how we return `int` from this function so that it takes up one less byte. `int`s can be implicitly cast to `bool` so it's fine.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchLCsIwEADQtZ5iEhBmEIsrQYKHyc8aaJOQjGZRevZYXNW3fK73MOdUGCo7FSJDxsolxBEaLcXzu0QQ2IZnmpyQ@vwwl/tN4pVObZh8HPlFau2fFBzMOkQkWI4HXasvjBmlNtZIIrU/a@1fie2Md79b@xc)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 9 bytes

```
.{+}*\,%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfrZSYlJykpKCUnJwMJBMTE4FkQWlRKpAqzy9KAVJJqSAyOT8FJJYEomKr/@tVa9dqxeioKv6vVc3T@g8A)

## Explanation

```
.{+}*\,%! | whole program
 {+}*     | sum the codepoints of the string
.    \,   | push the length
       %  | modulo
        ! | logical negate
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 73 bytes

```go
func(R[]rune)bool{s:=0
for _,r:=range R{s+=int(r-'`')}
return s%len(R)<1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBNasMwEIXpVqcYDCYSdUqyKBRTZdGuugvpMg2J7EhG1JGMfpJFyEm6CYUeKj1NJctN6Ub6Rk8z7zEfn40-X547Vr-zhsOOSYXkrtPG3WVi57JrYZ2RqrH_Hmqt9hlCe2ZA0C_vxPjh8iK8qvFiuTJecVJp3R5tSSdIaAPrwpTUMBWMFkd7S6Vy2IxHmxE5IcOdNwps3nKFF-RxekoDv2_u48Q-GSZwRFJ13lkoKWxYVVclOOM5qut6IMbYQJ03fMCDNtsBKx5IsNaGJr3lv1z98QYNaVupeDRKkV-7Vjqc7AvI3lQW4_CW92GSGjuCVkJGQtDwHOXlZIUOTLliHT_OmbH8KewF99p0RVCjXVQETlsLHoSgedi3EzjLLYxngHNHIHdAZ-EM1gVIVUA_FUJ7QqA0FgSd0LC98zndPw)

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##bc1BCsIwEIXhfU4xBIQERXRbzR1KtyIySRMptkmZJrooPXutFVxIlvMx/O8e5h7NA@8WOmw8a7o@UIQ9d13kjD2RwIGaXfJGVJcrJW@lDqEdh0IdmAsEtx0VitAvhWoctqrxUZCcGNmYyMOwaa0XlTwfp7WyzggJIwMoC1XS8t/60@cSTnwXBEdtNJdS/rsxJseImOM@kc35K1Cdc22zbEKdzeifT/Mb) (using TIO because ATO isn't working for me for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 42 bytes

```swift
{$0.utf8.reduce(0){$0+Int($1)}%$0.count<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc7BCsIwDAbgu08RyoSW6djAgwz14M2zR/XQZq0MRjtqyg5jz17b5vKRPyHkt4yGTnHSBKYH/iQ/2q@A4w3uzk1wjWvVNoHMufF6CKh5K1JSPyzxqhPbPk3RBUuXbovGeVicH2C08GJSoWIHYIiYkVJm5uB1Nu9llS6gG0qssh9Yd5BqTr8QLxdrYD28uSmdEEzstvgH)

This uses the same algorithm as the current top answers for Python, Excel, Java, and Scala, and probably others. As for why I use `.utf8`, see my explanation [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243585). As with that answer, the input type here can be `String` or `Substring`, and the output type is `Bool`.

It still surprises me that Swift has `.reduce(0, +)` rather than `.sum()` for collections of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## APOL, 32 bytes

`v(0 i);!(%(⊕(ƒ(⁰ ⌕(ⓛ ∋))) l(⁰)))`

Explanation:

```
v(            Set memory cell
  0
  i           to input
);
!(            Not
  %(          Modulo
    ⊕(       Sum
      ƒ(      List-builder for
        ⁰     Memory cell 0
        ⌕(    Find
          ⓛ  All ASCII lowercase characters
          ∋   Loop item
        )
      )
    )
    l(        Length of
      ⁰       Memory cell 0
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7\log_{256}(96)\approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
OSz0L%!
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbL_YOrDHxUFSE8qOCCJYlJyUkQNgA)

##### Explanation

```python
OSz0L%!  # Implicit input
 S       # the sum of
O        # the ords of the input
     %!  # is divisible by
    L    # the length of
  z0     # the input?
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 67 bytes

```php
fn($w)=>!(array_sum(array_map('ord',str_split($w)))%96%strlen($w));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XdDbCsIwDAbg@z5FhI61IOxOEJ0@iMhIu5YKmys9OIb47HWnq96Fj@QPiTU2Xe/WWKDj4FoPNTwIQIlCivIIVQXBxWCmxaSUOSFiTjY6ldsSnZtQO2ns/JY/tCojkdHzQgjVUCf9ZnTk9e3A0DmcGh/7verRsnLd54NrvO1eYWnlvDifipk6tY7yS9KDUygNsP109PMTOHznxR90TRt7y6jemskv/QE)

**Ungolfed**

```php
fn($w) => !(array_sum(
    array_map('ord', str_split($w))
  ) % 96 % strlen($w));
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
:VR1=
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3AVR1%3D&i=abcb%0Accc%0Aaaa%0Apure%0Aword%0Abed%0Acode%0Abode&m=2)

This program's length is the same packed and unpacked, so I chose to use the unpacked version.

## Explanation

```
:V    # mean of array (returns a fraction)
  R   # denominator
    = # is equal to
   1  # 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 40 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P02jXNNWUaO4NFcj09ZQR7lcJyw1uTg3MScHKBGdGatraaapqlyu@b@gKDOvRCNNQykxKTlJSVOTCy6QnJyMwk9MTEThF5QWpaIIlOcXpaAIJKWi8pPzU1B1JEEE/gMA)

```
f(w)=!(sum(i=1,#w,Vecsmall(w)[i]-96)%#w)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <s>67</s> 59 bytes

```lua
s=...a=0s:gsub('.',load'a=a+(...):byte()-96')print(a%#s==0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/2FZPTy/R1qDYKr24NElDXU9dJyc/MUU90TZRWwMopWmVVFmSqqGpa2mmrllQlJlXopGoqlxsa2ug@f///4LSolQA)

Ungolfed version:

```lua
s=...
a=0
s:gsub('.',load'a=a+(...):byte()-96')  -- Add up value of chars, store in a
print(a%#s==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [minigolf](https://github.com/jfioasd/minigolf), 12 bytes

```
i+,ni#*i+=;+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=3VjJkts2EK3KIQflmB9AOAeTFsVI8jbRlFzlxNmXcRJnVaZUEAlJGFMkA4CakX8lF1_iU77IX5NucBdBju3KKSxViSS6X--NJv56mRzUNo5evHrnPb5LYqGIPMhBfkvFJqFCssFA_wkyL195j8Qm3bFIPdErdsCkL3iieBzNrR2P-CYO15YzOCEZq0eDYElzHvvWmofslgurXZc6JAzESSWcQvoRxGgPACZW6qMWwGxJFQu2VCJllpl0y8IECZ8IHilSqE32TEiEsNexIP6W-c94tCGPnp6TNAmoYtKxOrXy_zutzlOVpIqEXCoSr4kfByyJQVFJKPzQN6AWagLiJTDkCuk_VEnasMbXGDPp7WdaVoKW2tZ-7N0BTnzDrrmyx0CJ-CjWsgZ_p2o9Ov2HD92In9zmw_nZMHv16v13cV0q6j8D2sUFCIhASVk-4J0NOeRJFfDIE4wGtjO0_ogsx5NJCLL0_QBdywmP4CcXs9HkItMP1A1ZZHOHPCTjWekePxWYfWxPQ1grXwM1JoqNyw6Z63yZNXyaaefRJGFRYKMr7R1N7FgErgZ1nAqNhZL1cWv6msEaLXsqXy95cA1L48EgYOssIjY6dqZTmYweaq5MimAyDVXmOXzWLgmu3cwvLIKUEpBtmt-Z1Y3maKt1Zs3ICdAFS-Bs6K3YLqlwi-tqC1WXS12Ax8kHAOJas1YSFuwZqZfEie1ckKF-3yAOgapO1FjMF3LnLcIC4cjhYEKstkz08OYRF0ylIsrXMgevQ6oU5At1elyK3qSzVtJwnTFVOJqyyXBeovO-HHldVfdLme5KRZU4VDA5dbaeF6XPEtWiKPNXg7kUkldjixRcAHZoApdgm5nmgioP1O00-ADiAMgkjONmjCHXCF9MZs1cUjpDdB_oDH07AwuxwO1g9tUFM-pv25moxQgabZg9gcKA3gWvhhM0vE6HVkZLCjLBUqBo5zS6iLsZkdNebQSxZtaRnGwlJ8uYahQsLGtzpmszSJNudv2AdWhGkBpBXlEDBHK5xe30oogE3rsVhRH2tobdpSH5sMhvY4gq7eoZojsotDEja8vCon7q_jxyqNasLnBqEKgDj1L3zIfNkz9nLbnUJatmQrqd2akD3k5OvMpqWbUzSLOVdQ6ZyMltQp02djNJWgZnPQ8RSrsoIK36cVBgzSBg6PBqLdZDHWsYUCDW0C_eJs7HbC29srb2f4wwbFf0bYLbz1KP4ZCYO00thJEOIU4eMF6i8tgmCYd9FGI67W4ukRmOazjB_kwZDJURu1bE9g9-yH0nG3YaiLAzC5KkcktGEz12IAXhksAurg7ecT7pwS0bh1DY-AZPjCbOazhvE8YrGpJqurqpTJBuUZFftENYm9Rgk5-019d1EkzVyjBz0hzPfgbPz7Xni_TG7wkIAoV5-NBXlt21MoOmASurqmJkS7WSIavm5zwh6irWT5KoeMNacxdeb1xorJj-DY7UxlCTEUWHAa08o1N1pbrkEosViGzUq8P_uRrlrHkJPjIEvuy9lRu7Jff0iCNx2V4AFtLj3ofX8chw435QRPbN9oP5_IYNAcyxxpPpnbv37j84_Uhnoy5tUCmBFOJ7RgK-4aq7p2g7G99LJfCjjz95_Olnn3-hYSdjCOvkQTcQEAxrPN6a68nZiPzlV19_8-1350--_-HHpxp9NJkC_GjSDY8UwyPOThlYmz9p4LF3rxsTFo2sP2vW6b373aywaGT9JXfWuM9RYyPrrznr9G4f7_Sukfm3jHl62sM7PTWy_l6o3K8znibgvF19_nqCJSH1mW3FlgvT8Yl0I7l0z6zjAqwIl0g4PhsOe2hOkMadnAGNUzvr8PVHZXZ6kp2SSLIW8c5wlJJ9rRk-GLVNr__RWK4vxs2W_RA-xR63OyNIxO-4fEKGwm93ouvuAUb3RN6xF-WaXHZo2hDROhjxt8K9dAxDLV7mHboFBhgg3bBRFAR4AuRdgv-1yJDuVgEl8czKX8aw4Vwf62CWXUHWANEGcGjvyY6oK1u0heJYSwwG-TlZQ1FIJVeTAHR2HPbipUVX_srKnv4F)

### Explanation

```
i+         sum of codepoints of input
,          map in [1..sum(i)]:
  n          push curr. item
  i#*        Multiply by input's length
  i+=        Is that equal to input's sum?
;          end map
+          Sum the list
           (we definitely have a 1 output for an integer quotient,
            and 0 with no integer output

Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
SslḊ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhbLgotzHu7oWlKclFwMFVqwpKC0KBXCBgA)

##### Explanation

```python
SslḊ  # Implicit input, converted
      # to ordinals by B flag
S     # Sum the ordinals
 sl   # Get the length of the input
   Ḋ  # Is divisible?
      # Implicit output
```