# 10 PRINT CHR$(205.5+RND(1)); : GOTO 10 in PHP (or anything else, for that matter)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, random

Just had a 'spirited' conversation with a co-worker about the succinctness of the following BASIC statement:

```
10 PRINT CHR$(205.5+RND(1)); : GOTO 10
```

It's the title of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262018462), and will simply print a sequence of `/` and `\` characters, alternating between the two randomly, resulting in a pattern similar to this:

[image]

*(Image borrowed from http://www.flickr.com/photos/rndmcnlly/5058442151/sizes/o/in/photostream/)*

Being of a PHP proclivity, we wondered what the most compact way of writing the same thing in PHP would be, and came up with this:

```
while(1) { echo chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1)); }
```

`chr(47)` is a `/` character, and chr(92) is a `\`. So the statement `echo chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1));` will randomly alternate between the two, ad nauseam.

In a language of your choosing, write the shortest program or function to output an infinite random sequence of `\` and `/` characters, where each character has an equal probability of being chosen.

Comment: You can lose the `{}` braces, but that's about as concise as you can make it.

Comment: This is cool. What font can be used to get a similar image?

Comment: This (picture) reminds me of the first "program" I ever wrote on my commodore 64 straight out of the manual :) ah happy days

Comment: @daniero I think the actual typeface is called Terminal, but I found it online as "Windows Command Prompt" https://codepen.io/nickforddesign/pen/WMqQdM?editors=0110

Comment: What a strange coincidence that this Code Golf repo on Github happens to have the exact same challenge... https://github.com/noops-challenge/golfbot

Comment: It's a general pro tip: `for(;;)` is always shorter than a `while`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `goto` operator was added to PHP from version 5.3.0 so you could use the same method as you would in BASIC:

```
a: echo chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1)); goto a;
```

Answer (score 22):

Since this has been migrated to codegolf...

#### PHP 30 bytes

```
<?for(;;)echo rand(0,1)?~Ð:~£;
```

The `Ð` is character 208, and the `£` is character 163.

Sample usage (on a Windows box):

```
color 18 & php maze.php
```

Produces something similar to:

[image]

It works best with a monospace font that is exactly square (here I've chosen the standard system font 8x8). To go back to your default color, you can type `color` again without any parameters.

Comment: Can save an extra byte with `rand()%2` (nobody stated _how_ pseudo-random it had to be) - Also doesn't work on Unicode terminals (like OSX)

Comment: @Leigh Due to its implementation, `rand()%2` will alternate between zero and one. `mt_rand()%2` would work, however.

Comment: Ðis is really nice. Bring back þorn!

Answer (score 20):

## Mathematica 157 bytes

Lacking PETSCII, I rolled my own "\" and "/".

No cigar for brevity here.

```
Graphics[{Thickness[.005],RGBColor[0.73,0.55,1.],Line/@Flatten[Table[RandomChoice[{{{x,y},{x+1,y+1}},{{x+1,y},{x,y+1}}}],{x,40},{y,25}],1]},Background->Blue]
```

[image: blue maze]

Comment: This image does the grey dot optical illusion!!

Answer (score 11):

## Brainfuck - 534

```
>+[->>>>>>[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]>[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]<<<<+++++++[<+++++++++++>-]
<[<<[>>>>>>+<<<+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[>>>>>+<<<+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[>
>>>+[<<<+>+>>-]<<[>>+<<-]+<[>-<[-]]>[>+<-]<<-]<-]++++++[>++++++++<-]>-
[<<[>>>>>+<<<<+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<<[-]>[-]+++++[<+++++>-]<[>>>>>>>+[<<<<<<
+>+>>>>>-]<<<<<[>>>>>+<<<<<-]+<[>-<[-]]>[>>>>+<<<<-]<<-]++++++[>>>>>>+
++++++++<<<<<<-]>>>>>>[<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]++<[->-
[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[-]<[<<+>+>-]<<[>>+<<-]+>>[-]<[++++[>+
+++<---]>.[-]<<->]<[[>+<+++++]>----.[-]<]>+]
```

My prng (from [here](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#x_.3D_pseudo-random_number)) is both large and extremely slow. Perhaps a simpler LFSR or similar would suffice, but this works:

[image]

Comment: I think this is not random, though, since this is brainfuck.

Comment: most of these are relying on built-in prngs. Yeah, this will output the same every time. Could allow it to be seeded from keyboard at cost of a couple extra chars, but thats not really the point here, I think.

Answer (score 6):

## Befunge, <s>12</s> <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 7 Bytes

Edit: [James Holderness](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/62101/james-holderness) figured out an insane solution that uses three quotes instead.

```
?\","/"
```

Overflows the stack with a lot of excess characters for each symbol, but who cares when you can golf that 1 byte?

#### Old version

```
"/\"?>,#
```

<s>(Note the trailing space)</s> Trailing space apparently not needed (thanks MercyBeaucou)

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X0k/RsneTkdZ4f9/AA)

```
"/\" Adds both / and \ to the stack
    ? Chooses a random direction to go in. Both up and down loop back around to the ? so it's 50% chance to go in either direction.
Going left
"/\"  >,#  Adds \ and / to the stack but only print the second, the / before heading back
Going right
      >,# Prints the top of the stack, the \ before heading back
```

This does start to fill up the stack, with one extra symbol for every symbol printed.

Comment: looks like you can get rid of the extra space, as the `#` is at the end of a line. It's not consistent behavior, but the interpreter you're using allows it: https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X0k/RsneTkf5/38A

Comment: I also wonder if you are able to use only one `"`, but my attempts have been futile. Because you need a `/` on one side of the `"`, you will have to divide half the time.

Comment: @MistahFiggins Space definitely shouldn't be required for any standard Befunge-93 implementation. The code may fail in some Funge-98 interpreters, where the spec is more ambiguous, but adding a space wouldn't help in those cases anyway - you'd need a `<` after the `#` to make it work.

Comment: @MistahFiggins As for getting rid of one of the quotes, you can kind of do that in Befunge-98 by using `'` instead. [Try it online!](http://befunge-98.tryitonline.net/#code=LydcPz4sIw&input=)

Comment: @MistahFiggins I managed to get to 11 bytes using only one ". `? #,\"1/,#1` The problem lies with having to use 2 prints

Comment: @JoKing Just realised you can actually do better with three quotes! `?\","/"` Only downside it it'll overflow the stack much faster I think.

Comment: @JamesHolderness wow! I had gotten really close by using a high value instead of `\ ` so that it would divide to be `\ `, but I hadn’t thought about using 3. Genius.

Answer (score 5):

### C, 39 chars (38 on MSVC)

```
main(){while(putchar(rand()%2?47:92));}
```

[image]
[See it run.](http://ideone.com/CqYHL7)

On MSVC, we can replace `putchar()` with `_putch()` and save a byte, but it doesn't work in IDEOne.

```
main(){while(_putch(rand()%2?47:92));}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Common Lisp, 33

```
(loop(princ(elt"/\\"(random 2))))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Ø^XȮß
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjLiIE@sOz///HwA)

`XØ^ß` is a byte shorter, but prints a `0` before the slashes.

```
  X      Choose a random element from
Ø^       "/\",
   Ȯ     print it,
    ß    then call this link again.
```

Comment: I forgot `ß` can loop infinitely -_-

Answer (score 5):

### Python 3, <s>59</s> 51 bytes

Using only 1 line (in the spirit of the original 10 PRINT):

<s>`from random import*;exec("while 1:print(end=choice('\/'))")`</s>

```python
while 1:from random import*;print(end=choice('\/'))
```

Or (possibly not that random) using hash for just 47 bytes (but on 2 lines):

```python
x=0
while 1:x=hash(str(x));print(end='\/'[x%2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8LWgKs8IzMnVcHQqsI2I7E4Q6O4pEijQlPTuqAoM69EIzUvxVY9Rl89ukLVKFbz/38A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: It's [52 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0QjNS/FNj4@M7cgv6gkPl5DvSgxLyU/V11TLzkjPzM5VUM9Rl9dU/P/fwA) by using `__import__` (still on one line)

Comment: @Steffan Great improvement! Also helps slow it down to something more like the original :)

Comment: Here's a [46-byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vzwjMydVwdAqM8U2I7E4Q6O4pEgjM0VT07qgKDOvRCM1L8VWPUZfPTozRdUoVvP/fwA) version of your `hash` solution that's back to being a one-liner. :)

Comment: @DLosc Brilliant!!! Of course now I'm going to spend far to much time trying to shave another byte off ;)

Answer (score 4):

`print` has a return value of 1, so if you use that you can just wrap the whole expression in the `while`:

`while(print chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1));`

You can probably golf it further too.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
{k/℅₴
```

No trying it online

It was a smart choice adding all of the two byte constants of 05ab1e and Jelly.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 47 bytes

```c
main(){while(putchar(47+45*(rand()/(1<<30))));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6PCMzJ1WjoLQkOSOxSMPEXNvEVEujKDEvRUNTX8PQxsbYQBMIrGv//wcA)

Comment: 38 bytes: `main(){main(putchar(rand()%2?92:47));}`

Comment: Very nice! I have lots to learn golfing c, recursive main seems to be quite handy and rand mod 2 puts my monstrosity to shame!

Answer (score 3):

i try create using css style, and it's work

```
<style>
  body {
    font-family: monospace;
    line-height:75%;
    letter-spacing:-3px;
  }
</style>
```

this php code :

```
<?php
  $i=10000;
  while($i) {
    if($i%200 == 0) echo '<br/>';
    echo chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1));
    $i--;
  }
?>
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest an alternative style: `font-family: courier; line-height: 0.75em; letter-spacing: -0.25em;` Using `-0.25em` for letter-spacing seems to match up better than `-3px`, which has artifacts due to an inexact `pt` to `px` conversion.

Answer (score 3):

### ruby, <strike>27</strike> 23 chars

```
loop{$><<"/\\"[rand 2]}
```

`$><<` is 'print to stdout'.

Comment: You should be able to replace `"/\\"` with `'\/'`. Ruby 1.8 requires `[rand(2),1]` to produce the character instead of the ascii code.

Answer (score 3):

## C++, 45 Chars

```
int main(){for(;;)cout<<(rand()%2?"/":"\\");}
```

Not going to win any awards for shortness, but I had already written this when I heard about the mentioned book, so I just golfed it.

The putchar trick also works in C++, getting you down to 43, but you can't avoid declaring the return type on main.

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp - 68

```
(defun s(l)(elt l(random(length l))))(loop do(format t"~a"(s"/\\")))
```

Comment: Loop allows both a complex and a simple syntax, the simple one being like a progn, but looping forever. You can drop the `do`.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 68

In the "my language sucks at this" category, we've got Python!

```
import random,sys
while 1:sys.stdout.write(random.choice('/\\'))
```

Thanks to Ivo for a few chars on imports and `choice`.

Comment: Well, you're not saving anything with 'from sys import*' - if you instead write 'import sys,random' and use sys.stdout and random.random, you'll save 5 bytes.

Comment: Python3:
import random
while 1:print(random.choice('/\\'),end='')

Comment: @Ivo, Thanks, I forgot about choice!  You can keep py3, though.  ;)

Comment: If you reverse your string, you do not have to escape the backslash, thus saving a byte.

Answer (score 3):

### 16-bit x86 assembly code, 10 bytes

I don't remember if this one ended up in the book.

```
init:
scasb            ;read from where ES:DI points and compare to AL 
                 ;this sets flags similar to a subtraction 
salc             ;set mask in AL to 00 or FF 
and   al,'\'-'/' ;begin choosing character (AL is 00 or 2D) 
add   al,'/'     ;finish choosing character 
writec:
int   29h        ;write char in AL 
jmp   init       ;loop endlessly
```

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>26</s> 31 bytes

<s>eight</s> three bytes shorter than yours (without whitespace or braces)<s>,

two bytes shorter than [primo´s solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9170/55735) (without the tag)</s>.

PHP 5.4.9 was the current version in December 1012, so ...

```php
for($s="\/";;)echo$s[rand()%2];
```

<s>requires PHP 5.5 or later for literal string indexing.</s>

Run with `-r` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f622d0f9cdb06e92357a2c243fe5aca069d1875f).

Comment: PHP 5.5 didn't exist at the time of the challange posting, but have a +1 anyway. Also, try `rand()&1` on a PHP build for Windows. You might be surprised.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
["/\"Ω?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/Wkk/RuncSvv//wE)

```
["/\"Ω?  - Full program
[          Start an infinite loop
 "/\"      ... Push the string "/\" on the stack
     Ω     ... Pick a character from the top of the stack, at random
      ?    ... Print without a newline
```

Comment: `[„/\Ω?` is better

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), 7 bytes

```
? '/,\'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//@3V1DX14lR//8fAA)

the `?` sends the IP either left or right, so either `/` or `\` is pushed before printing with `,`. When executing the `'/` or `\'` in the wrong order after printing, it just does things to the stack (divides or swaps), and then pushes an irrelevant character before repeating.

Comment: I was just proposing a different 7 byte Befunge-98 solution on Jo King's answer. But this approach looks neater.

Answer (score 3):

### [Keg](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Keg#Command_Glossary), 12 bytes

You do not have to worry about the evenness 0f the output, because the range is 0 to 32767, and 32767+1 = 32768; it is an even number.

```
{~2%[\\|\/],
```

Answer (score 3):

## HTML+JS, 186

```html
<pre style="letter-spacing:-3.5px;line-height:9px;;white-space: pre-wrap;line-break: anywhere;" onclick="setInterval(_=>this.innerHTML+='/\\'[2*Math.random()|0])">C l i c k   m e !</pre>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Uiua, 15 bytes

```
⍢(&pf⊡⁅⚂"\\/")1
```

This goes in an infinite loop, so to try this without having your browser hang, first go to [the Uiua pad](https://uiua.org/pad), click the settings icon, and change "Exec limit" to a low  number like 0.5 seconds. Then paste this code in and click Run.

Explanation: `⊡⁅⚂"\\/"` gets a random number between 0 and 1, rounds it to the nearest integer, and picks either `\` or `/` based on that. `&pf` prints that character without a newline. `⍢(…)1` is `do … while 1`.

I've found a couple other 15 byte solutions:

- [`⍢(&pf⊡⁅⚂.)1$ \/`](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0__4o2iKCZwZuKKoeKBheKagi4pMSQgXC8K) — You save a byte by using a raw string literal and dropping the extra backslash, but you have to define it outside of the loop, and use an extra byte to duplicate it each iteration, so it's not shorter.
- [`⍢(&pf+×45⁅⚂@/)1`](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0__4o2iKCZwZivDlzQ14oGF4pqCQC8pMQo=) — Multiply 45 by random 0/1, add that to `/`.

Answer (score 2):

Not much better. Needs php 5.5+ for the array dereferencing feature.

```
while(1) { echo ['/', '\\'][rand(0, 1)]; }
```

Comment: Never even thought of that, thanks!

Comment: Actually PHP supports subscripts for strings: `while(1)echo'/\\'[rand(0,1)];`.

Comment: it means the `for` version would be the same length than the current shortest PHP answer: `for(;;)echo'/\\'[rand(0,1)];`

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>54</s> 53 bytes

```java
v->{for(;;)System.out.write(Math.random()<.5?47:92);}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@BenjaminUrquhart* by replacing `print` with `write`, so `'/'` can be `47`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZY49D4IwFEV3f8Ub24EORmO0fkyOspi4GIdnKVKFlrQP1BB@O4K4ubybl9yce@5YY3RPHp3KMQQ4oLHNBMBY0j5FpSEeXoDamQQUOw1Rc6DMu2eA/Uvpkoyzsi@1k/4EQjIKYrCwga6Otk3qPJOSH9@BdCFcReLpDWl2QMqER5u4gvG1mO9mi9VyymXbyQFUVte8B/143/mil2NH8sbezhf8lxhNrVDMVnnOR6e2@wA) (times out after 60 sec).

```java
v->{                     // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(;;)                //  Loop indefinitely
    System.out.write(    //   Print:
      Math.random()<.5?  //    If the random decimal value in range [0,1) is below 0.5:
       47                //     Print forward slash
      :                  //    Else:
       92);}             //     Print backward slash
```

Comment: Java. 60. Bytes. Wow.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Hehe. I hadn't even noticed I'm about average in byte-count. Usually I'm just assuming Java is one of the highest byte-counts, only slightly competeable with BrainFuck or C# sometimes. xD (PS: I even golfed it to 59 :P)

Comment: You are not average, you have a too small byte count (assuming Java, not that too small isn't good). But, at least, this isn't **JAVA 8**, where I think it's longer...

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Hmm, isn't Java 8 shorter with `c->{for(;;)System.out.print(Math.random()<.5?'/':92);}` (**54 bytes**) Or did you mean Java 7 is longer than Java 8? In that case you are indeed correct.

Comment: Dunno, I said that, usually, Java 8 is longer, because I have experienced seeing such bytecounts. Fr though, I haven't been able to take a Java tutorial for anything, because it simply does not work.

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY49D4IwFEV3f8Ub24EORmO0fkyOspi4GIdnKVKFlrQP1BB@O4K4ubybl9yce@5YY3RPHp3KMQQ4oLHNBMBY0j5FpSEeXoDamQQUOw1Rc6DMu2eA/Uvpkoyzsi@1k/4EQjIKYrCwga6Otk3qPJOSH9@BdCFcReLpDWl2QMqER5u4gvG1mO9mi9VyymXbyQFUVte8B/143/mil2NH8sbezhf8lxhNrVDMVnnOR6e2@wA) by switching to `System.out.write` and replacing `'/'` with `47`

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Thanks! Need to remember that `write` when printing characters. o.Ô

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 bytes

I was hoping I could restrict it to a 3*3 square but didn't succeed.

```
"/\
~x/
o</
 !
```

You can try it [here](https://fishlanguage.com/playground).

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 12 bytes

```
D<^<!"/\"B!o
```

**[View in the online interpreter!](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=RDxePCEiL1wiQiFv&input=&speed=50)**

This maps out to the following cube net:

```
    D <
    ^ <
! " / \ " B ! o
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

### Explanation

**Setup:**

The IP begins heading east at the first `!`. This is the 'skip if truthy' command, which is False when there is nothing on stack, so no commands are skipped. `"/\"` enters stringmode and appends these two character codes to the stack. `B!o` is mostly a no-op here, only reversing the stack.

The IP now loops back around to the first `!`. However, there are now positive integers on stack, so the first `"` is skipped. This means `/` is no longer a character, but a mirror, sending the IP north into the main loop.

**Main Loop:**

The `D` command is the only source of randomness in Cubix. It sends the IP in a random direction. By blocking off South and East with arrows, we make sure the IP has a 50% chance of heading North, and a 50% chance of heading West.

If it heads West, the stack is reversed. If it heads North, the top character is printed.

This creates the random sequence of slashes, as desired.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 20 bytes

```
?"/\"[RND(2)];
EXEC.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://www.nodejs.org), <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

### Original Answer

```
while(1){process.stdout.write(Math.random()>=0.5?"/":"\\")}
```

### -4 bytes thanks to manatwork

```
while(1)process.stdout.write(Math.random()<.5?"/":"\\")
```

### -1 byte thanks to Conor O'Brien

```
for(;;)process.stdout.write(Math.random()<.5?"/":"\\")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: No need for braces around a single instruction block; in JavaScript the 0 integer part can be left out; reverse the conditional to use single character operator: `while(1)process.stdout.write(Math.random()<.5?"/":"\\")`.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks! Updated.

Comment: You can also write `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)`

Comment: Thank you as well. Added.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview), <s>108</s> <s>90</s> <s>86</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```powershell
for(){Write-Host "\/"[(Random 2)]-n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEOzOrwosyRV1yO/uERBKUZfKVojKDEvJT9XwUgzVjev9v9/AA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf. [Tips for golfing in PowerShell](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell)

Comment: [The Get verb is implied](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/191/tips-for-golfing-in-powershell/778#778) + [don't always need to provide the full name of a parameter, and some parameters are positional](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15290/80745)

Comment: `for` also makes `while` [a bit shorter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/199/80745)

Comment: you can more... more precisely, [less](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEOzOrwosyRV1yO/uERBN09BKUZfKVojKDEvJT9XwUgztvb/fwA "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Comment: and [less](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/Py2/SEOzOrwosyRV1yO/uERBKUZfKVojKDEvJT9XwUgzVjev9v9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 10 bytes

```
Du\'^>o$/;
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=RHVcJ14+byQvOw==&input=&speed=20)

```
    D u
    \ '
^ > o $ / ; . .
. . . . . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

Was an interesting one to do as i haven't played with the random direction generator much.

- `^D` redirect to the random direction pointer

Directed north

- `o\>` loops around the cube, print empty stack and redirecting back into the print commands (stack is empty)

Directed west

- `^` redirected back into the random direction pointer

Directed south

- `\'/>` reflected to the east, push / onto the stack and redirect into the print commands

Directed east

- `u'\>` uturn to the right, push \ onto the stack and redirect into the print commands

Print commands

- `o$/;^` output top of stack, skip over the reflect, pop from the stack and redirect into the random direction pointer

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 61 bytes

```
from random import*
while 1:print('/\\'[randint(0,1)],end='')
```

Pretty self explanatory. Had to use the double backslash since backslashes are escape characters in Python.

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocZVnZOakKhhaFRRl5pVoqOvHxKhHg5SAeAY6hpqxOql5Kbbq6pr//wMA)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 33

Just interested to see whether this can be made smaller.

```r
while(1)cat(sample(c('/','\\'),1))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/SjoerdPennings/Brasca), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
1[`/\`1?#$o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7V9vGEv/fn2ILbbGLDSaPJuFiUkjSlraEHKDn9h4uVdbW2lYqaRVpheH08dXTmdXDWmltrcKTc9qAtDvzm@fO7o6CKzHl/uPnQfjJ8QIeChJdRV3iUTFtjUPuEeF4jGSvXMaC5HFIfRv@SV/gX/DfhLXSByKkIzakoz9arZFLo4jshzQa0Vf4@3aLwM/KysqJgAFdErKJEwkWRgSokAsaOnTosggGyIE2GxPLcnxHWFY7Yu64s92SL/BnVdKQE3My@UscvBHJAQNydq4@p/Csrz4aKo/mPPZCRmYMGFDb8SeEXbAQtIa/0oiMphRkRb4vy4xDGGJ53GZA93vqRqyA@50TMLvn@MSmguaPnTHxuTQBTAdmG05Ehbhqd7bzIQX6MMDC6UB@PgNRtjtn29u9rXNl0piHxOoSiwBT5sceC6lg7RKpEiMNM7RXFLsCmapvzpBlt/K0jEO1zAYNAubbbR7a7YRwp5MPZ6CzOsnBS@Za/ZGiE6XGGTLmkwCMIJhNrpgo2Ye6qKorKxtRtdHp1InIzHFdEgkOPkDhNzFlZAgG/4MJEvDIEQ73Sx43mzous1zOgwiI/vm3QpGREToEOiySCjgyD1UCOMJK31S9dJQ4VFFu@Rwiz3VGECVg21wY/QjBA1Xc1XdxNCUwcQgcBZfQpHnyCAxggJUMkD7TxdEFb6laFN8XqV9QN2aEj@cRg5w0XPB9ygN/XcoE3UYO6iwWZMiFgFQFnJeKZSXj6qRz/IiFot1PhtQLaIQAZ6j8F0s@B1AVHuwqs3OJBQ@yxFlONDlZNcxCJuLQL3heNRLTIQVgyCaJ3RKaWhXwoCj8HcDsZxo7gTBGQNnikWOKmLCyh6lJsj9VfNlTMoCYpCuadEWzVDlXUIK1PHuomz2szi74XBH7WpS6oDaAMdndlERKCCYydvRy95uKWyU97OiV0k9NeIzrccS0Iss3Zacq8MlGdHJa0luQlMv8iZjqHTZ5V6abuhq8bM9ZFEIzdmHBldTkCkFwhSAu6IO0y@tGJ2c1jB3XTh6W@QnmBWphg08sqDuUmkN9CQujyz7GXDDFOlgcZMsZJB/uebhCVSsFXHxKNQKYtUJ6l/SrhURlVG9AtpRR0keqOAeLqZVkLQPLBEF3O1tJVl1lXjpRTz5zw0wxnSrYIoPzRgzAO0IsoiQjNTMsqibO5JxzmJQhqp@SjcRZcvpyGdZWajV9Gsas3rYD8mg5p/eNzVEcVgFhSh8n1pNPvamFe5CTK8hYHqHhBCLBF7B9CeSeCctA2NJsBFdkTHbGoHKfemy3@nZEdjBsdlutUw7xhJsbCO1hPOmSGPLW2N4cYagBF2pjvhlvjjZwaOTyGbH5zCc8FkEs0uHR5iiSwBzcFyFPy5ISW5ZHoS62UhMmAMAQha1X6mQptrySXPm0dfZ@8//vt16ufsnPP6XbsyRxkX3MQElKxITl0aBIo5ifslxHDgGHHC3/TrJdgWde2@7IZFl4U8xu4ZVqp9y4RVJnGrLn5SyQjlE2ZAs9rfJglciVdgcS4a5asS5JNn1NHBW0Vqym@9XArzjzljm5LQNyj8zJPTIg99ic3GMDck/MyT0xIPfUnNxTA3LfmpP71oDcM3NyzwzIPTcn99yA3Atzci8MyLkN3NgkLH5pQM/E81iDuDAx7psGgWESaHaDyDAx7@sGvmwSG9MG7mLizT828RcTh/m5EUETin@ubJPV12wUMiwOTIlnj7Ds65lk7L@RzYF/DTbrJmxCZCOXu2N5mqvjQ@crsL5slWBMBuGmw8FNhjw6bg@7hAJKvYUWSOh0WtUFWwqQrPZQLE1pWCv42vu1pY6hnuVqK2CjUroshTzqqiln1rfOO8sIKRXVOm6pqho5pLiVDXAjxwsH5Auxr6Mf7Nn2LTuAzmXXqYGf9hDfSTzEawZxDyB7JiC/QZCHsSucwL26B5DfmIDcTBKLYBPwHtu5cCLdtvL2wW5umqD9SqqU27HL7wHjVyYQf0eIby4D7i9K1LdsdSOzRzKAPobXQVhljreGG2PY@KW/RsCgTTsdXZLed8TMgf1sg6z0D4J@e3R6o5j/MVHX1zIfvn19D/b82gTfX4jv6Pge4P1lAs9CeL/dC77fAZ/G@060m/gKcIrAA3nQzueH13tLS4XixQEQMFDPUMtl35zL0ITLnuSS3cmYCaNeGphJs6/ns9@Aj5E8XeSTHuAvOJRROGQn/bWEt5GwHeNdqTywB1H4eAmHz8089DojK6j/o6Ke37eZAs@u4ExRZePpDUyoSOOhNB6/UNWP8ZEQ0bJMbr8@yxgZNknCAN9hjq@kaHn5lh581uNrqnNjfEGN/ogvG3sivV94PPaF6Q7On@/g@t1k6pI9nLGNbsZO72rs9ID0sNwXrukPL2WyTHq20u6Ifm/r0TNTv8sbvNqwzyyfK3QMAHyRr3Hzi9XapK05y0ivXk1YfoksoxkNpKHFjBNHMC8i3L92Mr/1jD80kO9Y2pSLbJES05Cxu5VxdOuKGF1HZdr7nIoeT1CPI@7juunnygR3SQhHd@8nGGORQJHW8R9qFGGTshiLHSDtHEA2a2sbH7jjS3Z@Z57I8oMv7GFYnPRGmOYgmRRSX@FKL51df6LXRDkI3kAdTqoOKPsEASKOgyk/zX3tnu58XBGqm6ZopQdCkWuxWAAlmbw7IE@ep22t@PfOgDx9tniecuIILM4kEry6l9MBdL3cB0W5541wiQba63cmd18V@8VnSw2QW/ViX8ry1wEioV1fsi/1uwrt34q0TQprk0W9wiVGLr/6vRMtSd@0DJFdO0k0NztJh2Rgm@SZX1Ock4U4iznlMskpl5Wc0qpzA7W16abF1JwJHGweGTgal0ctsiED27/3Tl4dHKRtjnVeN29FqPQeL2xHKIlSbVrWXkbgjxzSHk3Va6BOF8LaHqytGVj6aKGoJkFw/9LmwddEaF8VOs2gD9fAReM2EPPtYjEfqnE1hp0LrInnV9wXIXfJ9y6f1StkBxXyC4siqKPpbd@AoPp2aKPEtaWnxExU3bTdaBd18QOYR/aw3406dh@uOgbySudjDG59B4oYDB6sJtb@twaa2Gdixpj/ELaWqC@sLkf4v4frQN@hA52y0HNwY9a6maSIn3yxS0eY1JarCADyoS17galLPsReUJPYpdZRr/1afVRbEGoRfUBEPwEKrOZmUFhHTXoc1P6Zem4/5dzwm8Rm7Hoqu3UDdmfI7r/Y9tqTPbPVxuuqupOa9wssepdusJSdUm/rvMZCi6TKhSo2i9c202qlPS9JC0vybcm6e6uimnjSq@VdPaWP8Mw6hU4NaSaf7UmaLXXnknykIqUIQiYPZKL8e1X8JjJth6q2zOt7o/Vd8qun@H2LI6A0HJPZlPmwxefAOJRRJRywKbAdw@7drumPbtZvpX7HkqM5Qtayh0CeKzuiZZ7MK01YKbhSp8LqobxCyb7aLH@taZQC2eWIBYL8zK6GHBIP9tqEYRyI0sdP1WyeTnwj/4G0jYYsibN6wj2WfO06Y74gs5D7ky6eBPMZGIcAJ67CTUrplTfHx0fH20Q3vXT3mkzIv@fegHTtUWEBuPIhfEGE5DuAg9Rx0@8XWk03DvOxSgiAj2l2GEvvea9xVEkHS6sQDUYMfT3G6maV1u3ZFhDXB@icNq2S1ZJL9Vklt0TsxiLXi9tc1IVi4s@nfwE)

### Explanation

```
1[         ]  - While 1:
  `/\`       -   Push \ and /
      1?      -   Push rand(0,1)
        #$    -   If truthy, swap the top two items, else skip.
          o   -   Print it!
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 19 bytes

```
D,f,,"\/"BX
Dx,$f,o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ01HRylGX8kpgsulQkclTSf//38A)

### How it works

```
D,f,,    ; Define a function, f
    "\/" ; Push "\/"
    BX   ; Random choice

Dx,      ; Do, while x:
   $f,   ; Set x to the result of f
   o     ; Output with no newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```py
from random import*
while 1:print(end=choice('\/'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5erPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCM1L8UWIqGXnJGfmZyqoR6jr66p@f8/AA)

Saves at least 9 bytes over other python solutions here.

Edit: saved a byte via ayreguitar's comment

Comment: Nice use of end! But as @Jonathan Frech pointed out in the first Python entry, no need to escape the \ if you reverse the order, saving 1 byte: `while 1:print(end=choice('\/'))`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use recursion.

```
function slashes() {echo chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1)); slashes();}
```

---

I guess you can use recursion.

```
function slashes() {echo chr(47 + 45 * rand(0,1)); slashes();}
```

---

```
...
```

Comment: stack space is not infinite.

Comment: @codaddict so it will timeout.

Comment: Assuming a considerably high timeout your snippet is not equivalent to the OP's.

Comment: @codaddict lol the OPs times out as well. it is an **infinite** loop!

Comment: Yours would create a run time error before the timeout.

Comment: @codaddict no errors, just a timeout: http://codepad.org/nR6IunfF

Comment: http://ideone.com/euCb5Z here you go *SIGSEGV*

Answer (score 1):

chopped off one character:

```
while(1) { echo chr(2 + 45 * rand(1,2)); }
```

then remove the curly braces:

```
while(1) echo chr(2+45*rand(1,2));
```

another trick, with the same length:

```
while(1) echo chr(rand()%2*45+47);
```

Comment: Due to the algorithm it employs, `rand()%2` will result in an alternation of `0`s and `1`s. Not incredibly random. You'd need to use `rand(0,1)` or `mt_rand()%2` instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl

This one looks funny for me :

```
perl -pe '$_="~"ge$_?"/":"\\"' </dev/urandom
```

(Sorry to be out of subject here. I know this is not PHP)

Answer (score 1):

### Powershell, 37 bytes

```
for(){Write-Host(Random("\","/"))-N}
```

unfortunately there seem to be no shorter aliases for Write-Host that don't cause a new line after every char.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fission](https://github.com/C0deH4cker/Fission), 12 bytes

```
[#"\"R
W\"/"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8ssLs7Mz/v/P1pZKUYpiCs8Rklf6f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 53 bytes

```
while 1 {puts -nonewline [expr rand()<.5?"/":"\\\\"]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/PCMzJ1XBUKG6oLSkWEE3Lz8vtTwnMy9VITq1oqBIoSgxL0VD00bP1F5JX8lKKQYIlGJr//8HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth - <s>12</s> 9 bytes

```
#@,\/\\O2
```

Tested without loop code because the online interpreter dislikes infinite loops

Explanation:

```
#@,\/\\O2
#             Repeat until Error
 @            Implicitly print item number
       O2     random number between zero and two exclusive
  ,           of two item list containing
   \/         One character string /
     \\       One character string \
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 23 bytes

```
loop {<\ />.pick.print}
```

- `loop` loops forever.
- `<\ />` is a list of the strings `\` and `/`.
- `.pick` picks one of the two strings randomly.
- `.print` prints that random string.

Comment: instead of loop, you can use `xx*`

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 24 bytes

```
+1
W,R2,-1,*45,+47,H,x:1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bkCtcJ8hIR9dQR8vEVEfbxFzHQ6fCyvD/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [q/kdb+](http://kx.com/download/), 18 bytes

**Solution:**

```
while[1;1"\\/"1?2]
```

**Explanation:**

A simple while(true) loop...

```
while[1;1"\\/"1?2] / the solution
while[1;         ] / while true do ...
              1?2  / 1 choose 2 (0 or 1)
         "\\/"     / string \/, index in at 0 or 1
        1          / print to stdout without newline
```

**Extras:**

Another **18 byte** solution: `{1"\\/"1?2}\[::;1]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 27 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [@ayreguitar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/87219/ayreguitar)

`Mid$("\/",...)` is  used over `Chr$()` as the character codes for `/` and `\` are `47` and `92`, respectively.

While the `GoTo` structure of the original could easily be used for this [yabasic](/questions/tagged/yabasic) answer, `Do...Loop` ends up being shorter due to the the structure of the `Mid$` call.

```vb
Do?Mid$("\/",Ran(3),1);Loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0xMSizOTP7/3yXf3jczRUVDKUZfSSfI0U/DWFPHUNPaJz@/4P9/AA)

Comment: I don't know Yabasic, but from the TIO link you can save a byte by using "\/" instead of "/\\", like you can in Python (and I guess this works in some other languages)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
iOo"/\\"ö
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=aU9vIi9cXCL2)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 8 bytes

```
1Æû\/wq∟
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/wcNvh3TH65YWPOub///8fAA)

### Explanation

```
1          push 1
 Æ     ∟   do-while-true without popping using 5 operators
  û\/      push "\/"
     w     random char from string
      q    print without newline
```

Implicit popping doesn't seem to be working as intended when using do-while-true, or any other loop type. With this working correctly, the first `1` could be removed.

For a "working" 7-byter, you could do `t{û\/wq`, which replaces the do-while-true with a simple for loop, and begins the script by pushing the current timestamp in milliseconds to the stack. Currently, that means about \$1.56*10^{12}\$ iterations, which is "infinite" for most applications. However, this is not a valid answer, so the official answer is still 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

```apl
→≢⍞←'/\'[?2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jtkmPOhc96p33qG2Cun6MerS9USxI5r8CGBQAAA)

Tradfn body that prints indefinitely.

Thanks to @Adám for 5 bytes, and for pointing out that, with a little bit of CSS magic, [TIO can print the actual pattern like in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teggj.png).

#### How:

```apl
→≢⍞←'/\'[?2] ⍝ Tradfn body
         ?2  ⍝ Roll (randomly select) an integer between 1 and 2
        [  ] ⍝ Use the result to index...
    '/\'     ⍝ ...the string containing the two slashes
  ⍞←         ⍝ Print it to the same line
 ≢           ⍝ Tally the result (yields 1)
→            ⍝ then 'goto' that line
```

Comment: This is eligible for 200 rep, no?

Comment: @Adám is it? I've no idea why it would.

Comment: [This](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadline/17363#17363).

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess it is, then? There were no answers in any APL flavour before mine, and it meets all the conditions in the post. I'll add my request to it.

Comment: Cool, and feel free to dig up any of your posts from since February. I have way too much rep.

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 13 bytes

```
`/-R`A*+k$!;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z9BX5cpKMFRSztbRdH6/38A)

Slightly ungolfed for readability, with spaces to separate operational segments:

```
'/  2'RA  '- *+k $ !;
```

The difference of `45` is encoded in the `-` char literal, as chars are implicitly converted to integers when fed into a operator expecting a number value.

`2'RA` randomly generates a `0` or a `1`, multiplied against the `-` and added to the `/` char resulting in either `/` or `\`, which is then printed after being coerced back to a char from an int. In the golfed version the  (0x02) serves as the `2`.

Then the program loops forever by skipping the terminator, `!;`.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 12 bytes

```
x!\"/!
^o< <
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v0IxRklfkSsu30bB5v9/AA)

The idea here is to use `x` in combination with the `^` below to both loop and choose a random horizontal direction. If the IP goes left from the `x`, it will skip the mirror `/` and quote the string `"\!x!/"`, reflect upwards with `\`, wrapping around to the `<`, which redirects the IP to `o`utput the result and begin the loop again. If the IP goes right from the `x`, a similar thing will happen.

This is all thanks to the nice happenstance that `/` and `\` are control flow modifiers in ><>, allowing us to save a `"`.

An alternative solution for 13 bytes is slightly more generic and generates a lot fewer side effects.

```
xa!o"/\"o!a
^
```

(You can replace the `a`s with spaces; I have them placed here for clarity. In production code, you would want to do this replacement to avoid unnecessary stack population.)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 34 bytes

```
(loop[](pr(rand-nth"\\/"))(recur))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Zsh, 42 bytes

```zsh
for ((;;))printf ${(#)$((RANDOM%2?47:92))}
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/Lb9IQUPD2lpTs6AoM68kTUGlWkNZU0VDI8jRz8XfV9XI3sTcytJIU7P2/38A)

Answer (score 1):

## AppleSoft BASIC, 33 bytes

33 bytes, [verified here](https://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/)

```basic
1?MID$("\/",RND(1)+1.5,1);:GOTO1
```

35 bytes, using `CHR$` conversion similar to C64.

```basic
1?chr$(47+45*int(2*rnd(1)));:goto1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `qw`, 33 bytes

```
[ qw{ / \ } random write t ] loop
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQlJiXkp@rkJmvkJ1alJeao1BYrmD9PxpIVSvoK8Qo1MJUlBdllqQqlCjEKuTk5xf8/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua 5.4](https://www.lua.org/), 49 bytes

```lua
::a::io.write(2>math.random(2)and"\\"or"/")goto a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P/fyirRyiozX6@8KLMkVcPILjexJEOvKDEvJT9Xw0gTSCvFxCjlFynpK2mm55fkKwC1AAA)

Comment: also 49 bytes: `::a::io.write(({"\\","/"})[math.random(2)])goto a`

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 66 bytes

```python
import random
while 1:print(chr(47+random.randint(0,1)*45),end='')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP5erPCMzJ1XB0KqgKDOvRCM5o0jDxFwbIqcHokCiBjqGmlomppo6qXkpturqmv//AwA)

Ungolfed:

```python
import random
while True:
    slash_calc = 47 + random.randint(0, 1) * 45
    print(chr(slash_calc), end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 78 bytes (fixed seed)

```go
package main
import."math/rand"
func main(){for{print(string(`/\`[Intn(2)]))}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjfDCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSjT0lHITSzL0ixLzUpSs9ZTSckuUNLnSSvOSwao0NKvT8ouqA4oy80o0ikuAVLpGgn5MQrRnXkmehpFmrKZmbS3EeKgtMNsA)

Prints to STDERR.

#### Random seed, 107 bytes

```go
package main
import(."math/rand";."time")
func main(){Seed(Now().Unix())
for{print(string(`/\`[Intn(2)]))}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjeLChKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSjT0lHITSzL0ixLzUpSs9ZRKMnNTQXRabomSJldaaV4yWLWGZnVwamqKhl9-uYamXmheZoWGJlA6v6g6oCgzr0SjuARIpWsk6MckRHvmleRpGGnGamrW1kJshjoA5hAA)

Also prints to STDERR.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 143 bytes, `std` only

```rust
use std::hash::*;fn main(){loop{print!("{}",b"/\\"[std::collections::hash_map::RandomState::new().build_hasher().finish()as usize%2]as char);}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5LCsIwFEW3UgNCIn7Akbzuog6tlNc2JYE0KXkJgqVrcAFOOtBFuRur1dm9cA6c-8NHCuP4jKHZHF63SDKhUAMoJAWwShubtKgtF71xrus7r21YcNYPbF2yXZ6z0xevnDGyCtpZmt2ixQ4gQ1u79hgwSAArL1xsy6hNXXwQ6afbaKtJcYGURNJXudyfp1kp9CIdhjnrV_evfAM)

This mess is because the Rust stdlib (at the time of writing) has no "proper" RNG API. So, I had to use the workaround described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/fqbu0w/why_hasnt_something_like_the_rand_crate_been/flpr4pd/) to get a random number.

Answer (score 1):

## **Mathematica - 36 Bytes**

Barebones with no formatting. I don't know why the slashes are different thickness

```
Grid@RandomChoice[{"/","\\"},5{8,5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer! Looks like the thickness just has to do with the font, since it's only the backslashes that are thicker.

Answer (score 1):

## [Easyfuck](https://github.com/Quadruplay/easyfuck/wiki), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
ImúUt␗J»␀␒ű€
```

Decompressed:

```
$[?%+P.J]@␂/\
```

How?

````
$[?%+P.J]@␂/\

$             copy 1st cell into storage
 [      ]     while loop
  ?%+         set 1st cell to 1 or 2
     P.J      move pointer by signed value of 1st cell, print, move pointer to 1st cell
         @    beginning of initializer data
          ␂/\ initializer data (2, 47, 92)
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 40 bytes

```
For(I,1,8
For(J,1,16
Output(I,J,sub("/\",randInt(1,2),1
End
End
```

Outputs to the entire home screen for monochrome TI-83/84-series calculators. For the color calculators, replace 8 and 16 with 10 and 26 respectively, for +1 byte.