# Even or odd: three player

Tags: code-golf, number, game

It's a three players game, play with one hand.

At same time, each player show his hand with 0 to 5 fingers extended.

If all player show same kind of (even or odd) number, there is no winner. But else, the player showing different kind the two other win.

```
 P l a y e r s
A      B      C       Winner

Even   Even   Even    No winner
Odd    Odd    Odd     No winner
Even   Odd    Odd     Player A
Odd    Even   Even    Player A
Even   Odd    Even    Player B
Odd    Even   Odd     Player B
Odd    Odd    Even    Player C
Even   Even   Odd     Player C
```

The requested tool could use arguments (3 arguments as numeric between 0 and 5) or STDIN (3 values by line, separated by spaces).

There is no need to check input: Irregular input could produce unexpected output.

Arguments or values on line is given from left to right, from *player A* to *player C*.

Output must only contain `A`, `B` or `C` (capitalized) or the string `no one` (in lower case, with a regular space).

Tool may work only once or as a filter on all input lines.

Shortest code win.

Comment: Might be more interesting as a [king-of-the-hill]. *Play* the game.

Comment: I wonder how the fact we have 5 fingers (so there are 3 odd and 2 even numbers of fingers possible) affects the winning strategy...

Comment: @OlivierDulac, 0 is also an even number.

Comment: In this game rule yes, this let same chances for even than for odd numbers (0 2 4 vs 1 3 5)

Comment: @PeterTaylor: thanks, I misread the question (and I didn't think it would count).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### APL (<s>34</s> 30)

```
(1⍳⍨+/∘.=⍨2|⎕)⊃'ABC',⊂'no one'
```

Explanation:

- `2|⎕`: read a line of input, take the mod-2 of each number (giving a list, i.e. `1 0 1`)
- `∘.=⍨`: compare each element in the vector to each element in the vector, giving a matrix
- `+/`: sum the rows of the matrix, giving for each element how many elements it was equal to. If there were two the same and one different, we now have a vector like `2 1 2` where the `1` denotes who was different. If they were all the same, we get `3 3 3`.
- `1⍳⍨`: find the position of the `1`. If there is no `1`, this returns one more than the length of the vector, in this case `4`.
- `⊃'ABC',⊂'no one'`: display the string at the given index.

Comment: Nice, good use of array-oriented programming to compute the index.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>45 43 42</s> 41 chars

```
f="no one"[A,B,C]〚Mod[Tr@#-#,2].{2,1,0}〛&
```

#### Example:

```
f[{0 ,0, 0}]
```

> no one

```
f[{1, 3, 5}]
```

> no one

```
f[{2, 3, 5}]
```

> A

```
f[{2, 3, 4}]
```

> B

---

#### Another solution with <s>43</s> 42 chars:

```
f=Mod[Tr@#-#-1,2].{A,B,C}/._+__->"no one"&
```

Answer (score 5):

### Powershell, 65

```
param($a,$b,$c)"@ABCCBA@"[$a%2+$b%2*2+$c%2*4]-replace"@","no one"
```

Comment: Thanks. This gave me an idea on shortening [my Rock, Paper, Scissors script](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15386/9387)!

Answer (score 4):

### Befunge-98, <s>61 50</s> 45 characters

```
&&&:11p+2%2*\11g+2%+:"@"+#@\#,_0"eno on">:#,_
```

Uses Fors' clever expression to shave off yet a few more characters. Now single-line (i.e. Unefunge-compatible)!  Reads until a game is won; add `@` at the end for a one-shot program.

<s>Treats input mod 2 as a binary number, as with my JS answer, then relies on lookup for A-C and falls back to 'no one' if out-of-bounds (by testing if the character is ≥'A', which allows me to use nearby code as data :D).</s>

Variation that reads a line of input, produces output, reads a new line of input, etc until a game is decided (i.e. not 'no one'):

```
&2%4*&2%2*&2%++1g:" "#@-#,_0"eno on">:#,_
 CBAABC
```

Comment: I ported this to fish for my answer. I noted you. +1 btw

Answer (score 4):

## C: 88 characters

Unfortunately C, as always, requires quite a lot of unnecessary junk. But still, in which other language can one write `=**++b+**(++` and it actually means something? Quite simply sublime.

```
main(int a,char**b){(a=**++b+**(++b+1)&1|2*(**b+**++b&1))?putchar(a+64):puts("no one");}
```

Simply pass three numbers as arguments, and voilà!

Comment: Is the precise order of those preincrements specified? I thought it wasn't... although, you could replace them with `*b[1]` etc for no size difference (though some loss in elegance.. :( )

Comment: In Ruby: `s = "=**++b+**(++"` :P in all seriousness, wow, how does that... how does that even work? :O

Comment: @Doorknob it's very clever, but if you substitute the dereferencing and preincrements with indexing `b` instead, and pretty-print the condition some, you should be able to figure it out. :D (pen and paper also helps, for the resulting truth table)

Answer (score 4):

### APL, 30

```
(1+2=/2|⎕)⊃'BA'('C',⊂'no one')
```

If I am allowed to change system variables by configuration, 2 chars can be shaved off. (Specifically, changing index origin `⎕IO` to 0)

**The crucial bit**

If we represent all odds the same way and all evens the same way, then a pair-wise equality operation can distinguish all 4 cases: `0 0` for B wins, `0 1` for A wins, etc.

**Explanation**

`2|⎕` Takes input and mod 2
`2=/` Pair-wise equality
`1+` Add 1 for indexing (APL arrays are 1-based by default)

`'BA'('C',⊂'no one')` Nested array
`⊃` Picks out the correct element from the nested array

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 61 chars

```
w=0
$*.map{|p|w+=w+p.to_i%2}
$><<%w(no\ one C B A)[w>3?w^7:w]
```

Comment: `['no one',?C,?B,?A]` == `%w(no\ one C B A)` (2 chars saved).

Comment: Nice. Applied that. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (31 chars)

```
~]{1&}%.$1=!?)'no one
A
B
C'n/=
```

Very simple logic: reduce the input modulo 2, then sort a copy. The middle item of the sorted array is in the majority, so look for an index which is different (and hence in the minority).

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby (function body), 42 chars

Assuming 3 numerical arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
['zCBAABCz'[a%2*4|b%2*2|c%2],'no one'].min
```

## Ruby (command line tool), 61 chars

Version 1 comes in at 62 chars:

```
$><<["zCBAABCz"[$*.reduce(0){|i,n|i*2|n.to_i%2}],'no one'].min
```

But, by piggybacking off of [Darren Stone's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15562/10826), Version 2 gets down to 61 chars:

```
i=0;$*.map{|n|i+=i+n.to_i%2};$><<['zCBAABCz'[i],'no one'].min
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 54

```
f=lambda a,b,c:[['no one','C'],'BA'][(a^b)&1][(a^c)&1]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### JavaScript (node), 87 characters

```js
p=process.argv;console.log("ABC"[3-Math.min(x=p[2]%2*4+p[3]%2*2+p[4]%2,7-x)]||"no one")
```

To get the ball rolling... expects input as three extra arguments.  Makes use of the following pattern for input/output (`/` represents "no-one"):

```js
  A B C  res  #
 ───────────────
  0 0 0   /   0
  0 0 1   C   1
  0 1 0   B   2
  0 1 1   A   3
  1 0 0   A   4
  1 0 1   B   5
  1 1 0   C   6
  1 1 1   /   7
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl, 84 characters.

```
$x=oct"0b".join"",map{$_%2}<>=~/(\d)/g;print"",('no one','C','B','A')[$x>=4?7-$x:$x]
```

- `<>=~/(\d)/g` parses the input line into distinct digits
- `map{$_%2` takes this list and computes value mod 2 (even or odd)
- `oct"0b".join"",` takes this list of mod values, joins them into a string, appends an octal specifier, and converts the string to a number.

Basically what I did was to create a truth table, and then carefully reordered it so I had an inversion operation around `$x == 4`.  So if `$x >=4`, we did the inversion `[$x>=4?7-$x:$x]` which we used to index into the array `('no one','C','B','A')`

Its not the shortest possible code, but its actually not line noise ... which is remarkable in and of itself.

Perl: 74 characters + 3 flags = 77, run with `perl -anE '(code)'`

```
s/(\d)\s*/$1%2/eg;$x=oct"0b".$_;say"",("no one","C","B","A")[$x>3?7-$x:$x]
```

This is an improvement, by leveraging autosplit (the -a), say (the -E), and finally figuring out what was wrong with the comparison.

Comment: Why `>=4` instead of simply `>3`? +1 for the tips `'0b'.` I didn't know before

Comment: I tried both in the debugger ( >3 and >=4), and I am not sure why, but the >=4 worked, but >3 did not.  I can't explain it (possibly borked debugger?) to my own satisfaction either

Comment: you seem to have had an extra char in both counts, which I fixed. Also, flags count as characters.

Answer (score 2):

#### GolfScript, <strike>36</strike> <strike>35</strike> 33 characters

```
~]0\{1&\.++}/'no one
C
B
A'n/.$+=
```

Takes input as described from STDIN. You can also test the code [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIwIDAgMSIKCn5dMFx7MSZcLisrfS8nbm8gb25lCkMKQgpBJ24vLiQrPQ%3D%3D&run=true).

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 97

```
main=interact$(["no one","A","B","C"]!!).(\x->min x$7-x).foldr(\y x->x*2+mod y 2)0.map read.words
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, <strike>114 106</strike> 70 chars

From the three values create a pair representing difference in parity between adjacent elements. Treat that as a binary number to index into result list.

```
(defun f(a b c)(elt'(no_one c a b)(+(mod(- b c)2)(*(mod(- a b)2)2)))))
```

Older algorithm:

```
(defun f(h)(let*((o(mapcar #'oddp h))(p(position 1(mapcar(lambda(x)(count x o))o))))(if p(elt'(a b c)p)"no one")))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica <s>100 94</s> 89

```
f=If[(t=Tally[b=Boole@OddQ@#][[-1,2]])==1,{"A","B","C"}[[Position[b,t][[-1,1]]]],"no one"]&
```

---

**Testing**

```
f[{5, 3, 1}]
f[{2, 0, 4}]
f[{0, 1, 2}]
f[{0, 1, 3}]
f[{1, 3, 0}]
```

> "no one"
> "no one"
> "B"
> "A"
> "C"

Answer (score 1):

### R 67

```
z="no one";c("A","B","C",z,z)[match(2-sum(x<-scan()%%2),c(x,2,-1))]
```

Comment: Interesting! How could I test this? What do I have to run (maybe a shebang?)

Comment: You'll need to start an interactive R session (e.g. `/usr/bin/R`) then enter the code above. `scan()` is what will prompt you for the input: an example would be to type `1[space]3[space]5[space][enter][enter]` and you will see the corresponding output (here, `no one`) printed to the screen. You can download R here: http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Answer (score 1):

## C, 85 chars

```
main(int j,char**p){puts("C\0A\0B\0no one"+((**++p&1)*2+(**++p&1)^(**++p&1?0:3))*2);}
```

Not as short as my Ruby answer but I'm happy with it, considering the `main` cruft.

Answer (score 1):

**Fish - 41**

```
:&+2%2*$&+2%+:"@"+!;$!o :?#"eno on"!;ooo<
```

Stole FireFly's befunge answer and ported it to fish because using registers in fish allows us to shave off some characters. Lost a few characters on not having the horizontal if operator though.

This takes parameters in through arguments.

```
python fish.py evenodd.fish -v 2 2 2  
no one
python fish.py evenodd.fish -v 2 3 2  
B
python fish.py evenodd.fish -v 2 3 3  
A
python fish.py evenodd.fish -v 3 3 4  
C
```

Comment: Ooooooooooo nice!

Comment: Hm, fish huh. Do you have trampoline? if so, maybe you could use (the equivalent of) `#@...<` at the end to save a char. Oh, and your current code looks like 42 chars to me, so decrement that char-count of yours. :)

Comment: @FireFly thanks! That did save a char, and you're right, I was over counted by one. My text editor said "col 43" at the end. But of course, cursor on an empty line says "col 1".

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk, 128 characters

```
[:c|o:=c collect:[:e|e odd].k:=o collect:[:e|o occurrencesOf:e].u:=k indexOf:1.^(u>0)ifTrue:[#($a $b $c)at:u]ifFalse:['no one']]
```

send `value:` with a collection

Answer (score 1):

## C <s>101</s> 96

C, probably the most trivial example (some ternary operations):

```
main(int v,char** c){(v=c[1]==c[2]?c[1]==c[3]?0:3:c[1]==c[3]?2:1)?puts("no one"):putchar(v+64);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6) / CoffeeScript, 50 bytes

Uses the truth table as per [Firefly's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15549/22867) but takes a more direct approach in character access:

```js
f=(a,b,c)=>'CBAABC'[(a%2*4+b%2*2+c%2)-1]||'no one' // JavaScript
```

```coffee
f=(a,b,c)->'CBAABC'[(a%2*4+b%2*2+c%2)-1]||'no one'  # CoffeeScript
```

#### Demo

```js
// Translated into ES5 for browser compatibility
f=function(a,b,c){return'CBAABC'[(a%2*4+b%2*2+c%2)-1]||'no one'}

//f=(a,b,c)=>'CBAABC'[(a%2*4+b%2*2+c%2)-1]||'no one'

for(i=6;i--;)
  for(j=6;j--;)
    for(k=6;k--;)
      O.innerHTML += i + ', ' + j + ', ' + k + ' => ' + f(i,j,k) + "\n"
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 18 bytes

```
eB"0CBA"ṁi0"5FZᵃ”r
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIjWzF8MHw0I11cbiNbMHwzfDAjXVxuI1sxfDB8MCNdXG4jWzB8Mnw1I11cbiNbMXwwfDAjXVxuI1swfDJ8MyNdXG4jWzB8MHwwI11cbiNbMXwzfDUjXVfGmyIsImVCXCIwQ0JBXCLhuYFpMFwiNUZa4bWD4oCdciIsIiIsIiIsIjMuMS4wIl0=)

-11 bytes thanks to [@Aaroneous MIller](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/101522/aaroneous-miller)

#### Explanation (Outdated):

```
euL1=["5FZᵃ”|:1Cv[0Ḟ|1Ḟ}kAi­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
e                            ## ‎⁡Calculate every element of list if it's even
 uL1=                        ## ‎⁢Contains only even or odd integers?
     ["5FZᵃ”                 ## ‎⁣If so, print "no one" 
            |                ## ‎⁤else
             :               ## ‎⁢⁡duplicate
              1C             ## ‎⁢⁢how many even integers the list has
                v            ## ‎⁢⁣decremented
                 [0Ḟ         ## ‎⁢⁤If the number of the even integers is 1, find 0
                    |1Ḟ}     ## ‎⁣⁡if not, find 1
                        kA   ## ‎⁣⁢uppercase alphabet
                          i  ## ‎⁣⁣index
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIjWzF8MHw0I11cbiNbMHwzfDAjXVxuI1sxfDB8MCNdXG4jWzB8Mnw1I11cbiNbMXwwfDAjXVxuI1swfDJ8MyNdXG4jWzB8MHwwI11cbiNbMXwzfDUjXVfGmyIsImVCXCIwQ0JBXCLhuYFpOmFbfFwiNUZa4bWD4oCdIiwiIiwiIiwiMy4xLjAiXQ==) for 20 bytes (the header is just to set up some test cases)

Comment: Actually, make that [18 bytes](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIjWzF8MHw0I11cbiNbMHwzfDAjXVxuI1sxfDB8MCNdXG4jWzB8Mnw1I11cbiNbMXwwfDAjXVxuI1swfDJ8MyNdXG4jWzB8MHwwI11cbiNbMXwzfDUjXVfGmyIsImVCXCIwQ0JBXCLhuYFpMFwiNUZa4bWD4oCdciIsIiIsIiIsIjMuMS4wIl0=)

Comment: @AaroneousMiller Done!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 49 bytes

```perl
$_=(0,C,B,A,A..C)[oct"0b".s/./$&%2/ger]||"no one"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lbDQMdZx0nHUcdRT89ZMzo/uUTJIElJr1hfT19FTdVIPz21KLamRikvXyE/L1Xp/38DAwMuAwNDLgNDIG1oyGUI5BsC@YZAvqGh4b/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnpANf91C3IA)

Takes input as three digits with no spaces between.

Answer (score 0):

### Game Maker Language, 116

My new answer relies heavily on FireFly's formula:

```
a[1]="no one"a[2]='A'a[3]='B'a[4]='C'return a[(3-min(b=argument0 mod 2*4+argument1 mod 2*2+argument2 mod 2,7-b)||1)]
```

The **old** code compiled with uninitialized variables as 0, **183** characters:

```
a=argument0 mod 2b=argument1 mod 2c=argument2 mod 2if((a&&b&&c)||(!a&&!b&&!c))return "no one" else{if((a&&b)||(!a&&!b))return "C" else{if((a&&c)||(!a&&!c))return "B" else return "A"}}
```

**Edit #1** - Whole different code

Comment: Interesting!? I didn't know this language before! But as this language does permit the use of array, this code seem not to be the smallest possible for this job.

Comment: @F.Hauri Yes, I'm trying to use arrays to get it shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 115

```
l=[int(x)%2for x in input().split()];0if[print("ABC"[i])for i,x in enumerate(l)if l.count(x)%2]else print("no one")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Two different method in two different languages + variations -> 6 answers

There are essentially 2 way for this operation:

- **`array`** based: Built a binary number of 3 digit, than take answer from an array
- **`count`** based: Count even and odd, and look if there is a `count == 1`

#### Perl 71 (array based + variation)

```
s/(.)\s*/$1&1/eg;$==oct"0b".$_;$==$=>3?7-$=:$=;say$=?chr 68-$=:"no one"
```

One of *my* shortest perl:

- `s/(.)\s*/$1&1/eg;` transform a string like `1 2 3` into `101`
- `$==oct"0b".$_;` transform binary to oct (same as dec, under 8)
- `$==$=>3?7-$=:$=;` if *`> 3`* oper `7-`. (From there `no one` == 0)
- `say$=?chr 68-$=:"no one"` if not `0`, print char from value, else print `no one`.

#### Perl 71 (array based)

```
s/(.)\s*/$1&1/eg;$==oct"0b".$_;say@{["no one",qw{A B C}]}[$=>3?7-$=:$=]
```

slightly different in the print step: The output is based on an *'array'*.

#### Perl 81 (count based)

```
$c=A;map{$a[$_%2]=$c++;$b[$_%2]++}split;say$b[0]==1?$a[0]:$b[0]==2?$a[1]:"no one"
```

Different meaning:

- `$c=A`   Initialise a counter *c* with `A`.
- `map{$a[$_%2]=$c++;$b[$_%2]++}split` Counter *b* count even and odd, *a* only store which one
- `say$b[0]==1?$a[0]:`  if *even* counter == 1 ? also print *even* player.
- `$b[0]==2?$a[1]:` if *even* counter == 2 ? also print *odd* player.
- `:"no one"` else print `no one`.

#### Bash 85 (array based)

```
c=$((($1%2)<<2|($2&1)*2+($3%2)));((c>3))&&c=$((7-c));o=("no one" C B A);echo ${o[c]}
```

This is based on my second perl version:

- `c=$((($1%2)<<2|($2&1)*2+($3%2)))` make the index pos.

  - $1%2 transform first arg in binary by using `mod`
  - $2&1 transform second arg in binary by using `and`
  - <<2 *shift-to-the-left* is same than `*4`
  - *2 *multiply by 2* is same than `<<1`.
- `((c>3))&&c=$((7-c))` if c >= 4 then c = 7-c.
- `o=()` declare an array
- `echo ${o[c]}` based on array

#### Bash 133 (count based)

```
a[$1&1]=A;a[$2&1]=B;a[$3&1]=C;((b[$1&1]++));((b[$2&1]++));((b[$3&1]++))
case $b in 1)echo ${a[0]};;2)echo ${a[1]};;*)echo no one;esac
```

- `a[$1&1]=A;a[$2&1]=B;a[$3&1]=C` store player into variable *a[even]* and *a[odd]*
- `((b[$1&1]++));((b[$2&1]++));((b[$3&1]++))` count *even/odd* into b.
- `case $b in 1) echo ${a[0]}` in case even counter==1 print even player
- `2)echo ${a[1]};;` case even counter==2 print odd player
- `*)echo no one;esac` else print `no one`.

#### Bash 133 (count based)

```
a[$1&1]=A;a[$2&1]=B;a[$3&1]=C;((b[$1&1]++));((b[$2&1]++));((b[$3&1]++))
((b==1))&&echo ${a[0]}||(((b==2))&&echo ${a[1]}||echo no one)
```

Same version, using bash's condition and command group instead of `case ... esac`

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 114

```
r=[0,3,2,1,1,2,3,0][int("".join(map(str,(int(x)%2for x in input().split()))),2)];print("ABC"[r-1]if r else"no one")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 80 chars

```
r=int(input().replace(' ',''),2)
print(['no one','C','B','A'][7-r if r>3 else r])
```

Note: input must be '1' [odd] or '0' [even]. For example:

```
> 1 1 0
C
> 1 1 1
no one
```

Comment: The challenge requires the input to be "separated by spaces". Perhaps there is a way to effectively golf a `split` and `join` so you can still use your (very smart) `int(...input...)` idea.  ?

Comment: You could remove the `'0b'+` I think, at least it looks redundant to me, and just `int(input(),2)` seems to work in a REPL.

Comment: @DarrenStone I used a string replace instead, see edit

Comment: @FireFly Thanks, you're right, I edited my answer. I first tested the code with Python 2, where the '0b' was needed.

Comment: The challenge also requires the input to accept numbers from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure, 116

```
(fn[& h](let[a(map #(bit-and % 1)h)](["no one"\A\B\C](+(.indexOf(map(fn[x](reduce +(map #(if(= x %)1 0)a)))a)1)1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### vba, 116

```
Function z(q,r,s)
a="A":b="B":c="C":d="no one"
z=Array(d,c,b,a,a,b,c,d)((q And 1)*4+(r And 1)*2+(s And 1))
End Function
```

call with `?z(1,2,3)` or assign to a variable with `q=z(1,2,3)`, or even use as a UDF within excel, and use `=z(1,2,3)` in your excel formula

Answer (score 0):

Java, 226 chars

```
void func(int a, int b, int c){
    a = a%2;
    b = b%2;
    c = c%2;
    String out = "B";
    if((a+b+c)==0 || (a+b+c)==3)
        out = "no one";
    else if(a==b)
        out = "C";
    else if(b==c)
        out = "A";
    System.out.println(out);
}
```