# Cheating a multiple choice test

Tags: code-golf, array, bitwise

#### Introduction

While studying, I tried to come up with several ways to cheat a multiple choice test. It basically is a compressed version of the multiple choice answers. The method goes as following:

The answers to the test:

```
BCAABABA
```

These can be converted to 3 different arrays, which indicates true or false if the current letter is the answer:

```
    B  C  A  A  B  A  B  A
A: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
B: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
C: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Interpreting these numbers as binary would compress this a lot. But this can actually be compressed a bit more. If you know the positions of A and B, you don't need the positions for C. This can be done with a bitwise NOT operator:

```
A: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
B: [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

A+B: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
C:   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Converting the arrays A and B to binary numbers would result in:

```
A: 00110101
B: 10001010
```

That means that 8 multiple choice answers can be compressed to two bytes!

---

#### Task

Given two numbers in binary, or two arrays consisting of only 0's and 1's with the same length, output the multiple choice answers

---

#### Rules

- Input can be in the any form you like, like `[1, 0, 0, 1]` or `1001`.
- You may provide a program or a function.
- You may assume that the input is always valid.
- You may also output as a list, separated with spaces, etc.
- The multiple choice answers only consist of A's, B's and C's. You may however use lower case instead.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

---

#### Test cases

```
Input: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
Output: ABCABCA

Input: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output: BCBCACAA

Input: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output: CCCCCCCCCC
```

---

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=69770,OVERRIDE_USER=34388;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important;font-family:Arial}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Here is my solution. It is written in _English_ (interpreter freely available wherever you are), and is `Study.`. Six bytes. Beat that.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Sadly, _English_ does not meet [our standards of a programming language](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2073/34388) and is therefore not a valid submission :p

Comment: You can actually compress eight multiple choice questions to 1.625 bytes (13 bits) by interpreting the answers as base 3, so technically this isn't the most efficient method. :P

Comment: You could add another answer in the same space by using all four combinations of two bits, 00, 01, 10, 11 for answer a, b, c or d. You are not using 11.

Comment: @Doorknob another method: give 8 bytes for A, and find that of B only if the question's answer is not A. E.g. [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0] becomes [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,1], 12 bits this way, but may be any integer within [8,16], with a mean(or maybe not a mean) of 13.33333333333

Comment: How does taking input as "two numbers in binary" work with test case #3? That is, how can the program know that it's specifically the 10-bit representation of `0b0000000000`?

Comment: Now convert it to base 64 for maximum compression, and write it on your hand!

Comment: @TimPederick it can also be interpreted as a string.

Comment: @Adnan How doesn't it? It's Turing-complete and fulfills all the listed requirements.

Comment: Can we take the test an arbitrary number of times before taking it for reals.

Comment: *English* satisfies all the criteria. The only problem is there isn't an interpreter available before this question is asked.

Comment: @jimmy23013 Then perhaps a question should be asked to write an interpreter for English in as few bytes as possible.

Comment: @kasperd I've already written one! (31 bytes) Run `interpret ‘yourprogramhere’` (with quotes) in English to interpret an English program.

Comment: All it takes is one 'Choose all that apply' type question, and we're all screwed!

Comment: Why compress to 16 bits when you can fit it in ~13?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
_/ị“ḃ»
```

<s>Typing on phone. Will add description.</s>

`(1,0)` goes to `A`, `(0,1)` to `B`, and `(0,0)` to `C`. Arrays in Jelly are 1-based, and the indexing function `ị` works cyclically. Therefore, we can just fold subtraction over the input.

```
_              [vectorized] subtraction
_/             Fold subtraction over the input
   “ḃ»         "ABC" compressed. '»' terminates a compressed string.
  ị            Vectorized cyclic index.
```

Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Xy_hu4vigJxBQkM&input=&args=WzAsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDFdLFsxLCAwLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwXQ).

Comment: how on earth did you type that on a phone? o-O

Comment: Samsung's clipboard history. It wasn't easy.

Comment: :-DD And congrats on 10k!

Comment: Lol, same size as English now @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ

Comment: I golf my answer to "Study"; I am using an interpreter that is okay with grammatical mistakes. @RK.

Comment: English, -6- 5 bytes: `Blast`. Previous: `Touche`. Gave wrong output.

Comment: Just checking: do you even need the `»`? It seems wrong that Dennis' custom golfing language should require an unnecessary byte at the end of a program.

Comment: @ETHproductions Without it the interpreter thinks it's a normal string. I agree that it would be better to have a comprssed-string-start delimiter but I don't know how many symbols Dennis has free.

Comment: @ETHproductions http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26992106#26992106

Comment: I was really confused about the "ABC" thing until I remembered that strings are 1-indexed .

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>14</s> 9 bytes

```
2*+ 67w-c
```

Uses [current version (10.1.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/10.1.0)

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MiorIDY3dy1j&input=WzAsIDAsIDAsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDEsIDFdClsxLCAwLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwLCAwXQ)

### Explanation

**Summary of what the code does**

```
2*       % implicitly input array and multiply it by 2
+        % implicitly input array and add it to the first one
67w-    % subtract from 67
c        % convert to char. Implicitly display
```

**Detailed explanation of how it works**

```
2        % Push number 2 onto the stack
*        % Multiply the top two stack elements. Since there's only one
         % element, this triggers implicit input of a (yet inexistent)
         % element below the existing one. This is the first input array,
         % which will be called "A". Both "A" and number 2 are consumed,
         % and the array 2*A is left on the stack.
+        % Add the top two stack elements. Again, since there's only
         % one element (namely array 2*A) this triggers implicit input
         % of the second array, call it "B". Both 2*A and B are consumed
         % and 2*A+B is left on the stack
         % A blank space is needed after the "+" symbol to prevent it from
         % being interpreted as part of number "+67"
67       % Push number 67 onto the stack. The stack now contains, bottom
         % to top, 2*A+B and 67.
w        % Swap top two elements. The stack now contains 67 and 2*A+B
-        % Subtract top two elements. These are consumed and the result
         % 67-A*B is left on the stack
c        % Convert to char array, interpreting each number as ASCII code.
         % Number 67 corresponds to letter 'C'. Therefore at positions
         % where both arrays A and B were 0 this gives 'C' as result.
         % Where A was 1 and B was 0, i.e. 2*A+B is 2, this gives 'A'.
         % Where A was 0 and B was 1, i.e. 2*A+B is 1, this gives 'B'.
         % The stack contents, namely this char array, are implicitly
         % displayed at the end of the program.
```

Comment: This is amazing! Can you write a bit more about why this works? Why 67? And how does multiply input array by 2 and then add input array differ from 'multiply input array by 3'?

Comment: @Vincent Sure! I'll add some more detailed explanation later in the day

Comment: @Vincent Done! Let me know if it's clearer now

Answer (score 11):

## J, 8 bytes

```
'CAB'{~-
```

Usage:

```
   0 0 1 0 0 1 ('CAB'{~-) 0 1 0 1 0 0
CBABCA
```

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 44 bytes

```
T`d`BA
B(?=(.)* .*B(?<-1>.)*(?(1)!)$)
C
 .+
```

The trailing linefeed is significant. Input is like

```
001101010 100010100
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBkYEJBCkIoPz0oLikqIC4qQig_PC0xPi4pKig_KDEpISkkKQpDCiAuKwo&input=MDAxMTAxMDEwIDEwMDAxMDEwMA)

#### Explanation

```
T`d`BA
```

Start by turning `0`s into `B` and `1`s into `A`. That makes the first half correct, except that it lists `B` when it should contain `C`. We can identify those erroneous `B`s by checking whether there's a `B` in the same position of the second string:

```
B(?=(.)* .*B(?<-1>.)*(?(1)!)$)
C
```

The lookahead is a classic balancing group counting technique to match up the positions of the two `B`s. The `(.)*` counts the suffix after the first `B` by pushing one capture onto group `1` for each character. Then `(?<-1>.)*` pops from that group again. The `$` ensures that we can reach the end of the string like that, and the `(?(1)!)` ensures that we've actually depleted the entire group.

Finally, we get rid of the separating space and the second string:

```
 .+
```

Comment: 3 upvotes in the first 15 seconds of posting; that must be some kind of record.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Flattering, but I wonder how many of those 3 upvoters actually read and understood the answer in 15 seconds. :/

Comment: I did. I am rather fluent in reading regex and retina.

Answer (score 11):

### Java, 81 bytes

No reputation to comment the already existing Java solution, so here goes:

```
void x(int[]a,int[]b){int j=0;for(int i:a)System.out.printf("%c",67-2*i-b[j++]);}
```

Comment: This is smart. :D I like. I see that you got a teensy bit of inspiration, though. ;)

Comment: Damn, that's clever. I spent ages trying to figure out how I could get a foreach loop to fit...

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript ES6, 36 bytes

```
(a,b)=>a.map((x,y)=>"CBA"[x*2+b[y]])
```

Very simple, and probably obvious enough to understand: Map each item and index in `a` to the char at position (`x*2` + item at index `y` in `b`) in `"CBA"`.

Comment: Please add [this](http://pastebin.com/Er3R39SX) as your ungolfed version :3

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ He [`CBA`](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cba) to do that. Also, he can't anyway, because `do` is a reserved keyword, so that's invalid syntax.

Comment: @Patrick simple fix: Do(...)

Answer (score 9):

## brainfuck, 52 bytes

```
,+[->>----[<--->----],+]<[<[>--<-]<]>>[<,[>-<-]>.>>]
```

Requires an interpreter that lets you go left from cell 0 and has 8-bit wrapping cells. Unlike most of my answers, EOF behaviour doesn't matter.

Takes byte input, with `0xFF` as a delimiter. A stream of bytes representing the first input under "Test cases" would look like this:

```
0x01 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00
```

I could save a couple bytes by having `0x00` as a delimiter and using `0x01` and `0x02` as 0 and 1 respectively, but that felt like cheating :P

Once I figured out my strategy, writing this program was very easy. To find the nth letter to output, start with `0x43` (capital C in ASCII) and subtract ((nth element of first sequence)*2 + nth element of second sequence)

For what it's worth, here's the 52 byte program split into 3 lines and with some words beside them:

```
Get input until hitting a 255 byte; put a 67 byte to the right of each one
,+[->>----[<--->----],+]

For each 67 byte: Subtract (value to the left)*2 from it
<[<[>--<-]<]

For each byte that used to contain 67: Subtract input and print result
>>[<,[>-<-]>.>>]
```

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```haskell
zipWith(\x y->"BCA"!!(x-y+1))
```

An anonymous function. Use like:

```haskell
>> zipWith(\x y->"BCA"!!(x-y+1)) [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
"ABCABCA"
```

I tried making the function point-free but got a total mess. *2022 edit: Wheat Wizard found a version for 28 bytes, one shorter than nimi's 29-byte equivalent:*

```haskell
zipWith$(!!).(["CB","AC"]!!)
```

Comment: a point-free version of equal length: `zipWith((!!).(["CB","AC"]!!))`

Comment: A point-free version that's 1 byte shorter `zipWith$(!!).(["CB","AC"]!!)`.

Answer (score 8):

### Pyth, <strike>18</strike> <strike>16</strike> 10 bytes

**3<sup>rd</sup> attempt: 10 bytes**

Thank FryAmTheEggman for reminding me of the existence of `G`!

```
VCQ@<G3xN1
```

Input is of the form [ [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1] , [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0] ], which is essentially a matrix: row for choice and column for question number.

Hand-compiled pythonic pseudocode:

```
              G = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"    // preinitialized var
VCQ           for N in transpose(Q):    // implicit N as var; C transposes 2D lists
   @<G3           G[:3][                // G[:3] gives me "abc"
       xN1            N.index(1)        // returns -1 if no such element
                  ]
```

---

**2<sup>nd</sup> attempt: 16 bytes**

```
VCQ?hN\A?.)N\B\C
```

Input is of the form [ [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1] , [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0] ], which is essentially a matrix: row for choice and column for question number.

This compiles to

```
assign('Q',Pliteral_eval(input()))
for N in num_to_range(Pchr(Q)):
   imp_print(("A" if head(N) else ("B" if N.pop() else "C")))
```

Ok, I know that looks messy, so let's hand-compile to pythonic pseudocode

```
                 Q = eval(input())
VCQ              for N in range transpose(Q): // implicit N as var; transposes 2D lists
   ?hN               if head(N):              // head(N)=1st element of N
      \A                 print("A")           // implicit print for expressions
                     else:
        ?.)N             if pop(N):
            \B               print("B")
                         else:
              \C             print("C")
```

---

**1<sup>st</sup> attempt: 18 bytes**

```
V8?@QN\A?@Q+8N\B\C
```

With input of the form [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0], essentially concatenation of two lists.
This compiles to

```
assign('Q',Pliteral_eval(input()))
for N in num_to_range(8):
   imp_print(("A" if lookup(Q,N) else ("B" if lookup(Q,plus(8,N)) else "C")))
```

Again, compiling by hand

```
                   Q = eval(input())
V8                 for N in range(8):
  ?@QN                 if Q[N]:
      \A                  print("A")
                       else:
        ?@Q+8N            if Q[N+8]:
              \B              print("B")
                          else:
                \C            print("C")
```

---

And there goes the first codegolf in my life!!! I just learned Pyth yesterday, and this is the first time I ever participated in a code golf.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! This looks very nice for a first time, +1

Comment: Always nice to see someone learning Pyth! You can golf `.)` to be `e`, and I think it can be golfed quite a bit more. Consider the variable `G` which contains the lower case alphabet, I believe you can get to around 10 bytes using it, happy golfing! :)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman oh e! I was searching for it for several minutes! Also, thank you for reminding me of G. You are right, 10 bytes!

Answer (score 7):

## Python 3, 39 bytes.

Saved 1 byte thanks to FryAmTheEggman.
Saved 2 bytes thanks to histocrat.

Haven't been able to solve with a one liner in a while!

```
lambda*x:['CBA'[b-a]for a,b in zip(*x)]
```

Here's my test cases. It also shows the way I'm assuming this function is called.

```
assert f([1,0,0,1,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0,1,0,0]) == ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
assert f([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == ['B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A']
assert f([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == ['C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

It uses `zip` to iterate through the arrays pairwise, and then indexes into a string to pick the correct letter. This all happens in a list comprehension, so it automagically becomes a list. The core of this solution is that the only possible combinations of `a` and `b` are `[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 0]`. So if we subtract them, we get one of `-1, 0, 1` which gets us the last, first, middle element respectively.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, <s>30</s> <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 19 bytes

<sup>*3 bytes saved due to [@alephalpha](http://ppcg.lol/users/9288).*</sup>

```
{A,B,C}[[3-2#-#2]]&
```

Quite simple.

Comment: `{A,B,C}[[3-2#-#2]]&`

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 35 bytes

```
->a,b{a.zip(b).map{|x,y|:CAB[x-y]}}
```

Usage:

```
->a,b{a.zip(b).map{|x,y|:CAB[x-y]}}[[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]
=> ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Takes the (x-y)th zero-indexed character of "CAB". (1-0) gives 1, and thus A. (0-0) gives 0, and thus C. (0-1) gives -1, which wraps around to B.

Alternate shorter solution with weirder output:

```
->a,b{a.zip(b){|x,y|p :CAB[x-y]}}
```

Output is quoted strings separated by newlines, which seems a bridge too far somehow.

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, 13 bytes

```
¡#C-X*2-VgY)d
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=oSNDLVgqMi1WZ1kpZA==&input=WzEsIDAsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDAsIDFdIFswLCAxLCAwLCAwLCAxLCAwLCAwXQ==)

#### How it works

```
¡#C-X*2-VgY)d  // Implicit: U, V = input lists
¡              // Map each item X and index Y in U to:
 #C-X*2        //  The char code of C (67), minus 2X,
       -VgY)   //  minus the item at index Y in V.
            d  //  Convert to a char code.
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, <s>59</s> <s>57</s> <s>50</s> <s>37</s> 36 bytes

Takes one list from `Ans`, and the other from `Prompt L₁`. Saved 13 bytes thanks to Thomas Kwa's suggestion to switch from branching to `sub(`.

```
Prompt X
For(A,1,dim(∟X
Disp sub("ACB",2+∟X(A)-Ans(A),1
End
```

I'll have to look for what Thomas Kwa said he found in the comments tomorrow. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You still have some bytes to save! Replace the `Prompt L₁` with `Prompt X` and `L₁` with `∟X`. There's even more, but I'll let you find it.

Comment: @ThomasKwa L1 is a one-byte token, last I checked. Referencing it again with the list+x would be two bytes... am I not correct?

Comment: L1 is two bytes.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Oh. Dang.

Comment: I count 37 bytes as it is currently. (You can get 35.)

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 79

Saved 8 bytes thanks to Shepmaster.
Saved 23 bytes thanks to ker.

I'm positive this could be golfed down a lot, but this is my first time writing a full Rust program.

```
fn b(a:&[&[u8]])->Vec<u8>{a[0].iter().zip(a[1]).map(|(c,d)|67-d-c*2).collect()}
```

Here's the ungolfed code and test cases in case anyone wants to try to shrink it.

```
fn b(a:&[&[u8]])->Vec<u8>{
    a[0].iter().zip(a[1]).map(|(c,d)|67-d-c*2).collect()
}
fn main() {
    assert_eq!("ABCABCA", b(&[&[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], &[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]));
    assert_eq!("BCBCACAA", b(&[&[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1], &[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]));
    assert_eq!("CCCCCCCCCC", b(&[&[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], &[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]));
}
```

The approach is pretty similar to my Python answer. The main difference being that I can't directly index strings, so I can't do the `c-d` trick.

Comment: would it be legal to use a closure instead of a function? then you could skip all the types in the declaration and just pass `a[0]` and `a[1]` as two separate arguments.

Comment: also using the `64-y-2*x` trick from the Octave solution saves quite a few bytes due to being able to use `u8` instead of `usize`: http://is.gd/GNPK76

Comment: @ker I'm not totally sure about using a closure. I would assume it's okay, because it's essentially an anonymous function, right?

Comment: as long as you don't capture any surroundings it's exactly like an anonymous function.

Comment: @ker Then yeah, closure should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 19 bytes

```
@(x,y)[67-y-2*x,'']
```

Test:

```
f([1 0 0 0 1 1],[0 1 0 0 0 0])
ans = ABCCAA
```

I'll add an explanation later when I have a computer in front of me. This was written and tested on [octave-online](http://octave-online.net/) on my cell.

Answer (score 4):

## Vitsy, 40 bytes

*sigh* My baby was not made to do array manipulation.

Expects input through STDIN (something I never do) with a leading `"`.

```
WX&WXl\[68*-1+m]
?68*-2*"C"-i*O?
"B"O?X?
```

Explanation in the (soon available) verbose mode:

```
0:
STDIN;
remove top;
make new stack;
STDIN;
remove top;
push length of stack;
repeat next instruction set top times;
begin recursive area;
push 6;
push 8;
multiply top two;
subtract top two;
push 1;
add top two;
goto top method;
end recursive area;
1:
rotate right a stack;
push 6;
push 8;
multiply top two;
subtract top two;
push 2;
multiply top two;
toggle quote;
push cosine of top; // this is character literal "C"
toggle quote;
subtract top two;
push input item;
multiply top two;
output top as character;
rotate right a stack;
2:
toggle quote;
B;
toggle quote;
output top as character;
rotate right a stack;
remove top;
rotate right a stack;
```

This is getting golfed better real soon, people. I'm so sorry for its current length.

Basically, I treat the input as a string, and then manipulate from there.

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net)

Comment: :O Cannot wait until verbose mode. That will be interesting. Like the use of `W`!

Comment: @Adnan It is the input tab in tryitonline, but on the local interpreter, simply run the program and input each set of 0 and 1 with a leading " and a trailing newline while the program is running (`W` technically is prompt).

Comment: Ahh, I gave the input in the arguments section :p. Nice answer though :)

Comment: @Adnan It took me a while to figure this out - Vitsy autoparses input if it recognizes that it's a double. You can technically have a leading anything except for numbers, and it'll work the same.

Comment: Heh, that is quite weird, but on the other side it can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, 10 bytes

```
'Cq~z2fbf-
```

Input as a list of two lists, e.g.

```
[[1 0 0 1 0 0 1] [0 1 0 0 1 0 0]]
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code='Cq~z2fbf-&input=%5B%5B1%200%200%201%200%200%201%5D%20%5B0%201%200%200%201%200%200%5D%5D)

#### Explanation

Treating the pairs as bits of a base-2 number, we get `2` for `A`, `1` for `B` and `0` for `C`.

```
'C  e# Push the character C.
q~  e# Read and evaluate input.
z   e# Transpose the pair of lists to get a list of pairs.
2fb e# Convert each pair from base 2.
f-  e# Subtract each result from the character C.
```

Answer (score 3):

## R <s>29</s> 16 bytes

```
LETTERS[3-2*A-B]
```

removed declaration of function since I saw it's common in other contests.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>48</s> 45 bytes

I thought I had an elegant solution, then I saw @Morgan Thrapp's answer...

edit: Saved three bytes thanks to the aforementioned.

```python
lambda*x:['A'*a+b*'B'or'C'for a,b in zip(*x)]
```

<s>`lambda *x:[a*'A'or b*'B'or'C'for a,b in zip(*x)]`</s>

Comment: Ah nice. Didn't see `lamba*x:`. I always think it's as compact as can be then I get told/find even more tricks. I really like your solution btw, very nice.

Answer (score 3):

## Java, <s>131</s> <s>122</s> <s>110</s> 90 bytes

EDIT: Thanks to Bifz / FlagAsSpam for the help and inspiration

```
void x(int[]a,int[]b){int j=0;for(int i:a){System.out.print(i>0?"A":b[j]>0?"B":"C");j++;}}
```

<s>First submission, naive Java solution. Can almost certainly be improved :)</s>

```
static String x(int[]a,int[]b){String o="";for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)o+=a[i]>0?"A":b[i]>0?"B":"C";return(o);}
```

Comment: `==1` can be `>0`; it would also be better for you to return o rather than printing.

Comment: How about: `void x(int[]a,int[]b){for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)System.out.print(a[i]>0?"A":b[i]>0?"B":"C");}` (94 bytes)? You don't need the static declaration on functions.

Comment: You have to declare i first, +4 bytes :D

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 40 Bytes

```
param($a,$b)$a|%{"CBA"[2*$_+$b[++$d-1]]}
```

Takes input as two explicit arrays, e.g.. `PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\cheating-a-multiple-choice-test.ps1 @(1,0,0,1,0,0,1) @(0,1,0,0,1,0,0)`, and stores them in `$a` and `$b`. Next, loop through `$a` with `$a|{...}`. Each loop, we output a character indexed into the string `"CBA"`, with the index decided by twice the current value `$_`, plus the value of `$b` indexed by our helper variable that's been pre-added then subtracted.

As an example, for the first test case, `$a = @(1,0,0,1,0,0,1)` and `$b = @(0,1,0,0,1,0,0)`. The first loop iteration has `$_ = 1`, `$d = $null` (since `$d` hasn't previously been declared). We pre-add to `$d` so now `$_ = 1` and `$d = 1` (in PowerShell, `$null + 1 = 1`), meaning that `$b[1-1] = $b[0] = 0`. Then `2 * 1 + 0 = 2`, so we index `"CBA"[2]`, or `A`.

Answer (score 2):

## R <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```
function(a,b)c('B','C','A')[a-b+2]
```

Two bytes saved removing unnecessary braces

Comment: You can save two bytes by removing the braces in the function definition. They aren't necessary since the function body consists of a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

## , 12 chars / 22 bytes

```
Ⓒ…îⓜṃ-$*2-í_
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=%5B%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%5D&code=%E2%92%B8%E2%80%A6%C3%AE%E2%93%9C%E1%B9%83-%24*2-%C3%AD_)</kbd>

## Explanation

Translates to Javascript ES6 as

```
String.fromCharCode(...input1.map(($,_)=>67-$*2-input2[_]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 - 47

Already 30 answers and no perl? Here is a naive first attempt then :-)
Just the function:

```
sub x{($g,$h)=@_;map{$_?a:$h->[$i++]?b:c}@{$g}}
```

Usage:

```
@f = (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1);
@s = (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

print x(\@f, \@s);
```

I'm pretty sure that something better could be done with regex, but I couldn't find how.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, 75 bytes

I went the extra mile to accept integer arguments instead of array arguments.

```
(a,b)=>[...Array(8)].map((_,n)=>'CBA'[(a&(s=128>>n)*2+b&s)/s]).join('')
```

Explanation:

```
(a,b)=>              // input of two integers representing 8 answers (max value 255 each)
[...Array(8)]        // generates an array with 8 indices that allows .map() to work
.map((_,n)=>         // n is each index 0-7
'CBA'[...]           // reading character from string via index reference
      (...)          // grouping for division
       (a&...)       // AND operator to test if answer is A
          (s=128>>n) // calculating binary index in integer input and storing reference
       *2            // bias index in 'CBA' so truthy is 2 instead of 1
       +(b&s)        // AND operator to test if answer is B
      /s             // divide by binary index to convert AND operators to increments of 1
.join('')            // convert to string without commas
```

Credit to @ETHproductions for string indexing logic.

#### Test Here

```js
f=(a,b)=>[...Array(8)].map((_,n)=>'CBA'[((a&(s=128>>n))*2+(b&s))/s]).join('');

console.log(f(0b01001001, 0b00100100));
console.log(f(0b00001011, 0b10100000));
console.log(f(0b00000000, 0b00000000));
```

```html
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

#### Pssst

For 3 extra bytes, it can display the representation for up to 30 answers:

```
(a,b)=>[...Array(30)].map((_,n)=>'CBA'[((a&(s=1<<30>>n))*2+(b&s))/s]).join('')
```

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 46 bytes

```
^
%
+`%(.)(.* )(.)
$1$3,%$2
10
A
01
B
00
C
\W
[empty line]
```

Merges the two strings and chooses the letters according to the digit pairs.

[Try it online here.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 87 Bytes

Simply testing the values in the arrays, and concatenating `A`, `B` or `C`.

```lua
function f(a,b)s=""for i=1,#a do s=s..(0<a[i]and"A"or 0<b[i]and"B"or"C")end print(s)end
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 33 bytes

```
Seq.map2(fun a b->67-a*2-b|>char)
```

That's a partially applied function that takes two int sequences - two arrays work fine - and returns a new sequence of characters representing the correct answers. =)

Answer (score 1):

### Seriously, 14 bytes

```
,,Z`i-"CBA"E`M
```

[Try It Online](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LCxaYGktIkNCQSJFYE1Y&input=WzEsMCwwLDEsMCwwLDFdClswLDEsMCwwLDEsMCwwXQ)

Probably due to a bug in the safe mode version of the interpreter, you must add an `X` to get it to work right in the online version. Download the local version to get the above program working correctly as-is.

It's too short to warrant a full explanation, so I'll just say: it uses the same algorithm as the Jelly answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 45 bytes

This uses the multiif support from version 2.6.0.

```
f(u,v)=vector(#v,i,if(u[i],"A",v[i],"B","C"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 52 bytes

```
F(a,b,n){while(n--)putchar(a>>n&1?65:b>>n&1?66:67);}
```

The sequences of bits are interpreted as big-endian (MSB is the first answer), the third parameter `n` indicates the number of answers encoded.

Test main:

```
int main() {
  F(73, 36, 7);
  putchar('\n');
  F(11, 160, 8);
  putchar('\n');
  F(0, 0, 10);
  putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 41 bytes

**(52 if a sequence of chars is not a permitted output format)**

Finally a semi-cryptic Clojure answer :D Output as a sequence of characters:

```
#(map(fn[a b](or({1\A}a)({1\B}b)\C))% %2)
```

This version outputs a string:

```
#(apply str(map(fn[a b](or({1\A}a)({1\B}b)\C))% %2))
```

`{1 \A}` is a "dictionary" with key `1` and value character `A`. `({1 \A} a)` returns `\A` if `a` is `1` and `nil` otherwise, same logic for `b`. `or` takes the first "truthy" value, which is `\C` if both `a` and `b` are zero.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 10 bytes

```
~+†W∩vTkAİ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwifivigKBX4oipdlRrQcSwIiwiIiwiWzAsIDEsIDAsIDAsIDEsIDAsIDBdXG5bMSwgMCwgMCwgMSwgMCwgMCwgMV0iXQ==)