# Preparing a multiple choice test

Tags: code-golf, string, binary

#### Introduction

Note: this is not some kind of method to encourage cheating. As [Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69770/cheating-a-multiple-choice-test#comment170320_69770) already said, studying is the best solution for passing a test :3.

Consider the following answers to the multiple choice test:

```
ABCBCAAB
```

Here is a table which indicates whether the answers match:

```
    A B C B C A A B

A   1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
B   0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
C   0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```

This gives us the following numbers:

```
10000110, 01010001, 00101000
```

The challenge is to print these binary numbers. But it is **important** to see which letters are used in the multiple choice test. For example:

```
ABCDCDBCDABC
```

This **highest letter** is `D`, which is the *4th letter in the alphabet*. Therefore, we need to output **4 different** binary numbers. Namely:

```
100000000100, 010000100010, 001010010001, 000101001000
```

Note that you have to look at the *highest letter*. Consider the following example:

```
AACCACAC
```

Although the `B` is not used, we need to output the binary result for `B`. That means, the answer would be:

```
11001010, 00000000, 00110101
```

---

#### Task

Given the answers to a multiple choice test, output the binary numbers. **You may assume that the input will be non-empty and only containing the letters `[A-Z]`**
. Instead of ones and zeroes, you may also use true and false.

---

#### Test cases:

```
Input: ABBBABABA
Output: 100010101, 011101010

Input: AAAAAAAAA
Output: 111111111

Input: AFGHEEHFD
Output: 100000000 000000000 000000000 000000001 000011000 010000010 001000000 000100100

Input: Z
Output: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1

Input: ABCDCDBCDABC
Output: 100000000100, 010000100010, 001010010001, 000101001000
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the submission with the least amount of bytes wins!

Comment: Can we use `[a-z]` instead?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Of course :)

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69770/cheating-a-multiple-choice-test)

Comment: there are no rules for the output specified, is a 2D array of bools allowed?

Comment: that seems kinda unreasonable but works for me as well^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pyth, 12 bytes

```
mqLdzfsgRTzG
```

Outputs as a nested array of booleans.

```
                Implicit: z=input
m               Map lambda d:
 qLdz            map equal-to-d over z
     f           over all letters T in the
           G     lowercase alphabet for which
      s           At least one char in z
       gRTz       >= T.
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mqLdzfsgRTzG&input=afgheehfd&debug=0).

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, 71

Saved 22 bytes thanks to Ogaday.
Saved 3 bytes thanks to DSM.

Saved a bunch of bytes thanks to an array of bools being valid.

```
*k,=map(ord,input())
x=65
while x<=max(k):print([v==x for v in k]);x+=1
```

Takes uppercase command line input.

Comment: Use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/): `*k,=map(ord,input())`

Comment: An array of bools is now also possible, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, <s>95</s> <s>94</s> 73 bytes

```
param([char[]]$a)0..(($a|sort)[-1]-65)|%{$d=$_;-join($a|%{+!($_-$d-65)})}
```

Takes input as an uppercase string, but immediately casts it `[char[]]`. We then loop from `0..` to the maximal value of `$a` taken alphabetically (hence the `-65` to convert from ASCII). For example, with `ADCEB`, this can be thought of as looping from `A` to `E`.

Each iteration, we set a helper variable `$d` equal to the current alphabetical (not ASCII) value. We then loop through all of `$a`, each time putting either `0` or `1` on the pipeline, based on whether `$_-$d-65` is truthy or falsey (i.e., whether we're in the right "slot"). This works because any non-zero value in PowerShell is truthy, meaning if our current letter `$_` doesn't "equal" what slot we're in `$d`, then the `!` of that is `$false`, or `0`.

Each of those arrays of `0`s and `1`s is then `-join`ed together and re-put on the pipeline. When the outer loop ends, we have an array of strings, which will print one string per line.

#### Examples

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\preparing-a-multiple-choice-test.ps1 ABCDEFGH
10000000
01000000
00100000
00010000
00001000
00000100
00000010
00000001

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\preparing-a-multiple-choice-test.ps1 AFGHEEHFD
100000000
000000000
000000000
000000001
000011000
010000010
001000000
000100100
```

<sub>Edit 1 -- saved a byte by using Boolean-not instead of -eq</sub>
<sub>Edit 2 -- saved another 21 bytes by eliminating the extra array $b</sub>

Comment: An array of bools is now also possible, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

## LabVIEW, <s>30</s> <s>22</s> 20 [LabVIEW Primitives](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

Goes through from a-z until the sum of all bools is equal to the input lenght. then Transforms the bools to numbers.

Now directly takes the max instead of checking the bool sum.

Since 2D bools are viable now im saving 2 Primitives by outputting the green wire in front of `?1:0` could redo it but im too lazy...

[image: new code]
[image: old code]
[image]

Comment: An array of bools is now also possible, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 14  bytes

```
VhxGeSzmq@GNdz
```

Explanation:

```
               - autoassign z = input()
V              - For N in range(V)
 hxGeSz
    eSz        - max(z)
  xG           - lowercase_alphabet.index(^)
 h             - +1
       mq@GNdz
       m     z - [V for d in z]
         @GN   - lowercase_alphabet[N]
        q   d  - is_equal(^, ^^)
               - print "".join(^)
```

Outputs a 2D array of bools

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VhxGeSzmq%40GNdz&input=afgheehfd&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## Cjam, 25 bytes

```
l{'A-i}%_:e>),\f{f=", "}
```

Sigh,

### Explanation

```
l{'A-i}%_:e>),\f{f=", "}
l                        e# get the input
 {'A-i}%                 e# get the normalized array
        _:e>             e# get the maximum value
            ),           e# create the array from 1..N
              \f{      } e# map over the created array
                 f=      e# 1 if match, 0 if not
                   ", "  e# add separator
```

Comment: Congrats on 1k rep BTW!

Comment: An array of bools is now also possible, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, <s>46</s> 34 bytes

```
g x=(<$>x).(==)<$>['A'..maximum x]
```

Usage example: `g "ACDC"`-> `[[True,False,False,False],[False,False,False,False],[False,True,False,True],[False,False,True,False]]`.

How it works:

```
        <$>['A'..maximum x]   -- for every letter from A to the highest letter in x
<$>x                          -- loop over x and
      ==                      -- compare the letter with the current element in x
                              -- which results in a boolean
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 19 bytes

```
@(s)s==[65:max(s)]'
```

Uses Octave's automatic broadcasting over the range `A` to the max element in the input to produce 2d boolean array of matching elements.

Example:

```
Key = ABCDCDBCDABC

ans =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Try it here on [ideone](http://ideone.com/1mVbp6).

Answer (score 2):

### ES6, 92 bytes

```
s=>[..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"].map(c=>[...s].map(m=>m==c&&!!(l=n),n++),n=0).slice(0,l)
```

Returns an array of arrays of falses and trues. If you prefer an array of strings of zeros and ones, then for 97 bytes:

```
s=>[..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"].map(c=>s.replace(/./g,m=>m==c?(l=n,1):0,n++),n=0).slice(0,l)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, <s>208</s> 189 Bytes

That was tricky in lua, as usual, we have to do everything from scratch, and it takes a lot of place !
This program takes a string as argument, and print out the result :).

**Edit: @Adnan told me we're now allowed to return a matrix of booleans, so here's a new version! It is now a function that takes a string of capitalised character and return the matrix :).**

```lua
function f(x)a={}b={}for i=1,#x do a[i]=x:sub(i,i)end table.sort(a)for i=1,a[#a]:byte()-64 do b[i]={}end x:gsub(".",function(c)for i=1,#b do z=b[i]z[#z+1]=i+64==c:byte()end end)return b end
```

#### Old 208 Byte version

This is the one that works with argument and print results.

```
a={}b={}x=arg[1]for i=1,#x do a[i]=x:sub(i,i)end table.sort(a)for i=1,a[#a]:byte()-64 do b[i]=""end x:gsub(".",function(c)for i=1,#b do b[i]=b[i]..(i+64==c:byte()and"1"or"0")end end)print(table.concat(b,","))
```

#### Ungolfed and explanations

```lua
function f(x)
a={}                   -- We need 2 arrays, and while b=a would have been shorter
b={}                   -- arrays in lua are passed by pointer, so it wouldn't have worked

for i=1,#x             -- iterate over the inpute to transform the string
do                     -- into an array
  a[i]=x:sub(i,i)      -- with each cells containing a characyer
end
table.sort(a)          -- sort the array/string

for i=1,               -- iterate n times were n is the place in the alphabet
       a[#a]:byte()-64 -- of the last element of the (sorted) array a
do
  b[i]={}              -- initialise cells in b up to n with empty arrays
end                    -- a cell's index is the position of a letter in the alphabet

x:gsub(".",function(c) -- for each character in the input
  for i=1,#b           -- iterate over each cells in b
  do
    z=b[i]             -- define z pointing on the array b[i]
    z[#z+1]=           -- insert into b[i] the result of the
       i+64==c:byte()  -- comparison of the current char, and the answer
  end
end)
return b
end
```

Trying to print an array in Lua would result in printing its address and concatenating bools is impossible. So here's a function that will help you if you want to test this submission

```lua
function f(x)a={}b={}for i=1,#x do a[i]=x:sub(i,i)end table.sort(a)for i=1,a[#a]:byte()-64 do b[i]={}end x:gsub(".",function(c)for i=1,#b do z=b[i]z[#z+1]=i+64==c:byte()end end)return b end

function printBooleanMatrix(m)
  s="{"
  for i=1,#m
  do
    s=s.."{"
    for j=1,#m[i]
    do
      s=s..(m[i][j]and"1"or"0")..(j==#m[i]and""or",")
    end
    s=s.."}"..(i==#m and""or",\n")
  end
  print(s.."}")
end

printBooleanMatrix(f("ABBCCDDC"))
```

Comment: An array of bools is now also possible, if that helps.

Comment: @Adnan well, it allows me to drop a lot of bytes. I'm writing a function to have a clear output for testing purpose, then post a revised version :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>106</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> 87 bytes

Uses Windows-1252 encoding.

```
for($x=A;$x++<=max($z=str_split($argv[1]));print~Ó)for(;$c=$z[+$$x++];)echo+(++$c==$x);
```

Run like this (`-d` added for aesthetics only):

```
php -d error_reporting=30709 -r 'for($x=A;$x++<=max($z=str_split($argv[1]));print~Ó)for(;$c=$z[+$$x++];)echo+(++$c==$x); echo"\n";' ABCDDHFHUYFSJGK
```

- Saved 14 bytes by nesting the loops the other way around
- Saved 2 bytes by using variable variables to prevent `$i=0`
- Saved a byte by inverting string and dropping string delimiters
- Saved a byte by moving the echo (changed to a print to fit) inside the first for loop and dropping curly braces
- Saved a byte by incrementing `$x` somewhere else, and incrementing `$c` to compensate

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 84 bytes

```pl
$\="\n";@i=split//,<>;pop@i;for$c('a'..(reverse sort@i)[0]){print map{/$c/?1:0}@i;}
```

Oh dear, I seem to have broken the highlighter.

Ungolfed version:

```pl
# output formatting
$\ = "\n";
# get input chars as array
@i = split //, <>;
# lose the newline
pop @i;
# iterate over characters up to the max
for $c ('a'..(reverse sort @i)[0]) {
    # print 1 for each match, 0 otherwise
    print map { /$c/ ? 1 : 0 } @i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
->s{(?A..s.chars.max).map{|c|s.gsub(/./){c==$&?1:0}}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3TXXtiqs17B319Ir1kjMSi4r1chMrNIFEQXVNck2xXnpxaZKGvp6-ZnWyra2Kmr2hlUFtbS1E8-aC0pJiBbdoJUc3dw9XVw83F6VYiMyCBRAaAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
;m!aB
rÔò@®¥X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O20hYUIKctTyQK6lWA&input=WyJBIiwiRiIsIkciLCJIIiwiRSIsIkUiLCJIIiwiRiIsIkQiXS1S)

Input as an array of uppercase letters

```
;m!aB 
;       # B = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 m      # For each character:
  !a    #  Find its index in
    B   #  B
        # Store as U

rÔò@®¥X
rÔ      # Find the maximum value in U
  ò@    # For each value X in the range [0...maximum]:
    ®   #  For each value Z in U:
     ¥X #   True when Z == X
```

Alternate version in one line is [2 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O20hYUIgo1py1PKlWMN5&input=WyJBIiwiRiIsIkciLCJIIiwiRSIsIkUiLCJIIiwiRiIsIkQiXS1S) longer, unless it can output with rows and columns transposed.

Taking input as a string in either case requires 1 additional byte (`¬` before the `m`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 7 bytes

```
øA:Gɾv=
```

[Try it Online! (test suite)](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBciIsIiIsIsO4QTpHyb52PSIsIiIsIlsnQScsJ0InLCdCJywnQicsJ0EnLCdCJywnQScsJ0InLCdBJ11cblsnQScsJ0EnLCdBJywnQScsJ0EnLCdBJywnQScsJ0EnLCdBJ11cblsnQScsJ0YnLCdHJywnSCcsJ0UnLCdFJywnSCcsJ0YnLCdEJ11cblsnWiddXG5bJ0EnLCdCJywnQycsJ0QnLCdDJywnRCcsJ0InLCdDJywnRCcsJ0EnLCdCJywnQyddIl0=) Input and output as a list of characters of `[A-Z]` and list of booleans respectively.

```
øA:Gɾv= # whole program

øA      # convert each char to its alphabetical index (1-indexing)
  :     # duplicate
   G    #                                maximum
    ɾ   # convert into a range from 1 to         inclusive
     v= # for each num in the range, check if each converted chars == num
        #   (doubly vectorises)
        #   (the r flag swaps the arguments, giving the resulting command)
        # implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org), 52 bytes

```factor
[ 65 over supremum [a..b] swap [ = ] cartesian-map ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 68 bytes

```
c=>Enumerable.Range(65,c.Max()-64).Select(x=>c.Select(y=>x==y?1:0));
```

[Run in C# Pad](http://csharppad.com/gist/6f17d750299a8a091adb90cf836a4855)

This anonymous function takes a `char[]` as input and outputs an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`, with only 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 0):

## k, 15 bytes

```
{x=/:65_!|/1+x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7rCVt/KzDResUbfULuiFp2vbmClpJ@SWqZfXJKSmaf039HR2dkRCLkcnZycHEGQyxEGuBzd3D1cXT3cXLiigPLOLs4uQALIAAA)