# Print every character your program doesn't have

Tags: code-golf, self-referential

Your task is to build a program (using only printable ASCII characters and/or tabs and newlines) that prints out exactly the characters in the printable ASCII space (`0x20` to `0x7e`) that *don't* appear in your program's source code (in any order, however many times you want).

The shortest code to do this in any language wins.

Comment: tabs and newlines *are* printable ASCII characters.

Comment: They are, but they're not in the range `0x20` to `0x7e`, which are defined as the "printable ASCII characters". Technically tabs and newlines are actually control characters.

Comment: Are we allowed to print newlines (or any other unprintable ASCII characters)?

Comment: Tabs and newlines do not render in such a way that they occupy a printing position. They move the position. See the ANSI C "isprint" function.

Comment: What is the universal set, whose subset you ask to negate? I also do not understand were is the self-reference in all those answers.

Comment: @Val agreed, so far most answers just explicitly print out characters, rather than referring back to the original file.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr The program doesn't have to actually refer to its own source code. It just needed to, as I said, print out exactly those characters its source code doesn't have.

Comment: How did this question get revived? It's started getting upvotes again.

Comment: Ah, I see. It was posted on [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7150474).

Comment: I’m disappointed that you decided to restrict this to ASCII-based languages only. Otherwise `글⓵돠上字終` would have been a valid 6-character solution in [Sclipting](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Sclipting). It outputs all the ASCII characters and doesn’t have any of them in its source.

Comment: @Timwi: If you wanted to do that, you'd have to output all the characters in the CJK character space too (excluding the ones appearing in your code). It's too complicated to manage, so I restricted it to just ASCII.

Comment: "The shortest code to do this in any language wins." is unclear.   Do you mean there is a single winner, over all languages?  Or do you mean there's a winner per language?

Comment: Can we output non-ASCII characters as well?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I interpret as only print printable ASCII characters or (tabs and newlines)

Comment: Does it means writing a program contains all printable ascii as comment (or non-functional codes) and print nothing is valid? If so, any language who support comments should be able to do this in <100bytes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>15</strike> 12 characters

```
{`),32>^.}.~
```

Based on [Jan Dvorak's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12373/1490) with a few twists and also in the style of [Peter Taylor's one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12374/1490).

Answer (score 295):

## Polyglot, 95

```
#undef X;A!"$%&'()*+-[,.]/0123456789:<=>?@BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ\^_`abcghijklmopqrstvwxyz{|}~
```

- [Perl](https://www.perl.org/)
- [Perl 6](https://perl6.org/)
- Any *nx-like shell (`tclsh`, `bash`, `sh`, `ksh`, etc)
- [Awk (GNU / POSIX)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)
- [Brainfuck](http://esolangs.org/wiki/brainfuck), [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/m-ender/brian-chuck), other [derivatives](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_Derivatives)
- [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)
- [Coffescript](http://coffeescript.org/)
- [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/)
- [Python](https://www.python.org/)
- [R](https://www.r-project.org/)
- [Julia](https://julialang.org/)
- [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language))
- [rk](//github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang)
- [Gaot++](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/gaot-plus-plus)
- [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- [Joy](http://www.latrobe.edu.au/humanities/research/research-projects/past-projects/joy-programming-language)
- [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/)
- [99](https://esolangs.org/wiki/99)
- [V (FMota)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/V_(FMota))
- [Acc!!](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!)
- C - if no `main()` is needed. Thanks to [urogen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3544/ugoren)
- [Duocentehexaquinquagesimal](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Duocentehexaquinquagesimal)
- [Vyxal `O`](https://github.com/lyxal/vyxal)
- [Thunno `d`](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno)
- Probably more.

Does nothing.

Comment: Yes, but can you make it shorter?

Comment: No, but this is a polygot. I don't want to destroy that.

Comment: If you put the `[]` on the outside it will "work" in brainfuck too.

Comment: No. I have an output (`.`) in it. Wait...

Comment: Well, I have to skip the output (`.`) and input (`,`) so it will do nothing in brainfuck.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: that's what I meant by putting `[]` on the outside.

Comment: @marinus it suffices to put it after the hash

Comment: This will do weird stuff in C/C++

Comment: C/C++ is not on the list (a comment would require `//` or `/* */`)

Comment: I fed this into the GNU Fortran compiler and it segfaulted.

Comment: Count Ruby as one where this works. Also, coffeescript (I think)

Comment: In C, `#undef X;whatever junk you want` works.

Comment: @ugoren: No it won't, you need to define a main() function or it will not compile.

Comment: @ Johannes Kuhn: It wasn't a polyglot when I first saw it. (Tcl only at first :P) But now I see what you mean.

Comment: also, count in golfscript

Comment: Works in Python too (because it uses `#` for comments like Ruby and Perl)

Comment: @marinus, You're right. The line itself comiles, but it isn't enough.

Comment: _"The shortest code to do this in **any** language wins."_ For the lack of a code that works in _any_ language, this entry should win, since it's the code that works in the greatest number of languages. ;-D

Comment: @msb By "any" language, I mean "the language of your choice".

Comment: @JoeZ. I know, just kidding, trying to bend the interpretation of the definition to favour the most creative answer IMO. ;-)

Comment: Works in PowerShell.

Comment: Is it as polygot or a polyg_l_ot?

Comment: @msb, the OP would have said *The shortest code to do this in **every** language wins.*

Comment: q/k version is ``/ !"#$%&'()*+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~``

Comment: How is this valid BF? Extracting out only the BF instructions, we get `[,.]` which infinitly prompts for input and outputs it. So, if I input `A`, it will print `A` and then ask again. However, your code contains an `A`. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: but only if the current pos is not 0 at this point.

Comment: If an extra `"` is added at the end, it also works in Mathematica.

Comment: I believe this should be made into a community-wiki

Comment: Works with `><>`. If you move the `@` to somewhere before the `,`, it also works in Befunge-93. No way to make it work with 98

Comment: @JoKing It should work in `><>` already right? # will reverse then ~ will pop from an empty stack thus exiting the program

Answer (score 152):

### PHP 5.2, 4 + 69

```
<?<<
```

Save as a file called `` !"#$%&'()*+-.023456789;=>@ABCDEFGIJKMNOQRUVWXYZ[\]^`bfghjkmqvwz{|}~ ``. `short_open_tag` needs to be `On` in your `php.ini`.

The output is:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_SL in /wherever/!"#$%&\'()*+-.023456789;=>@ABCDEFGIJKMNOQRUVWXYZ[\\]^`bfghjkmqvwz{|}~ on line 1
```

Comment: Haha, nice bending of the rules.

Comment: I considered doing something similar with bash, but didn't because I thought it was too obvious to be interesting.

Comment: I believe `output` is assumed to be stdout. This does not print to stdout.

Comment: Not all filesystems support naming files things like that.

Comment: Doesn't work in newer PHP versions since they fixed the confusing error message (now it includes the "<" in the error). It's still a cool solution though!

Answer (score 52):

### JavaScript - 88

```
alert("BCDFGHIJKMNPQUVXYZ".toLowerCase())// !#$%&'*+,-0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~AERTOWS
```

prints "bcdfghijkmnpquvxyz"

Comment: Wow I like the toLowerCase idea, it's brilliant!

Comment: You can save three characters with a bit of math: `"!#$%&*+,-13:<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~AERTOWS";alert('BCDFGHIJKMNPQUVXYZ'.toLowerCase()+95*72)` because `95*72` = `6840` and moving the wasted characters to a string allows you to use the quotes instead of wasting them.  Besides that, hiding characters in a comment feels cheesy.

Comment: @Umbrella [82](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifmJNaVGJbUJSZV2L9X0lRWUVVTcfI2MrG1s7eITpGPzYuPqG6ptbRNSjEPzxYyRqsXEPdydnFzd3D08vb1y8gMDQsIjJKXa8k3ye/PLXIObE4VUNT29JUq87cUPP/fwA)

Answer (score 29):

#### Whitespace, <strike>61</strike> 57 characters

It's not the shortest but it probably has the simplest logic (it's just a loop really).

Here it is completely commented, where S is space, T is tab, L is line feed:

```
SSSTSSSSSL     # push 0x20
LSSSL          # label S
SSSTL          # push 1
TSSS           # add
SLS            # duplicate top of stack
SLS            # duplicate again
TLSS           # output ASCII character
SSSTTTTTTSL    # push 0x7E
TSST           # subtract (result - 0x7E)
LTTSL          # branch to label S if top of stack is negative
LLL            # end
```

Thanks to @r.e.s. for correction to the above (required extra duplicate for the branch instruction) and for smaller numbers to push on the stack.

Comment: This doesn't work as-is, but can be fixed by inserting a duplicate-top-of-stack (SLS) immediately before the conditional branch (LTTSL) -- it's needed because the conditional branch command removes the top-of-stack. The resulting 64-character program works as advertised. (If the program is stored in a file with .ws extension, it can be tested online at http://golf.shinh.org/checker.html)

Comment: Also, the program length can be reduced to **57** using nearly the same program but with the three pushed numbers -94, 127, 126 changed to 32, 1, 126, respectively: `SSSTSSSSSL LSSSL SSSTL TSSS SLS SLS TLSS SSSTTTTTTSL TSST LTTSL LLL`.

Comment: I know it's been over 5 years, but you can golf 5 bytes by changing the label S to label (empty) (`LSSSL` becomes `LSSL` and `LTTSL` becomes `LTTL`) and remove the exit at the end (the three `LLL`). [Try it online raw **52 bytes**](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgVMBBLi4gBjE4wLzwTxOLrAUJxgogCSAspxc//8DAA) or [here with highlighting and explanation](https://tio.run/##dY/BDoJADETP8BX@AnjwbPSiIUACN7JpylKFBHQDXf38laK4XswcmjTzOtNn2zFNBjU5VxUbURm8pygNIbdTC9sYFpOq0vCzP4yETJBgTT0kWZarL79SkarWY7BvGjEIDkdr@k4LzXfzbytnFjKzbCwDTqBbHFEzjT7Ky5eN4t0aXAZQ2JqFkurim12nC9zoitw9CM52MHPg7x/OvQA).

Answer (score 27):

### C, <s>83</s> <s>74</s> 69 characters

```
main(z) {for(;++z<96;"\33iE!vk?}GkRP8z"[z/7]&1<<z%7&&putchar(z+32));}
```

<s>I really tried to get it down below 80 characters, but I just haven't been able to pull it off. I finally decided to post what I have, on the assumption that I (or someone else) will figure out 79-character solution ten minutes after posting this.</s> Okay, it wasn't quite ten minutes, but it worked in principle.

I really wanted to post a version that didn't have to have a gratuitous space in the source code, but that one landed in a strange-attractor orbit, bouncing between a handful of solutions. After many minutes of trying to nudge one of them into a stable solution, I gave up and added the space.

Comment: 69 characters, nice

Answer (score 25):

#### ><> - 80

```
zbcdjkpqruvwxaABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#!"'$%^&*()@!+-[]{},;:/\<>=?|~0123456789
```

When fish errors it prints out "something smells fishy...". Since z is a bad instruction it errors right away

Answer (score 22):

#### Golfscript, <del>26</del> 24 characters

```
"126,32>''+".~\-'.~\-"'-
```

Takes a range generation script, duplicates it, executes it, substracts it from its result, then substracts the result subtraction code and the other quote character.

Comment: Damn, that's clever.

Comment: Remove `''+`, escape program before subtraction, put in a noop `.;` (didn't find a better way to cover the dot), use code block instead of string -> `{126,33>\`-.;}.~` which is 16 chars

Comment: And utilising *in any order, however many times you want* you can also remove the semicolon.

Comment: @Howard I'm afraid I don't understand your idea. You can post it as a separate answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I thought I printed a space?

Answer (score 19):

I know it's not winning any contests.  I just wanted to try it in a language not normally used, just for kicks.

## **Java - <s>209</s> <s>195</s> <s>152</s> 140 characters**

```
class a{public static void main(String[]a){for(char c=0;;c++)System.out.print("publicas{tvodmn(Srg[])h=0;w+ye.\"\\xO<?:}".indexOf(c)<0?c:"");}}
```

**With line breaks and tabs**

```
class a{
    public static void main(String[]a) {
        for(char c=0;;c++)
            System.out.print("publicas{tvodmn(Srg[])h=0;w+ye.\"\\xO<?:} ".indexOf(c)<0?c:"");
    }
}
```

Beware if you execute: program does not terminate.  Haha

**Explanation**

1. `for(char c=0;;c++)`: Since a `char` can be treated as an `int`, I use that to my advantage here to increment through all possible values of `c`.  I omit the terminating condition in the loop (the one that would go between the two semicolons) in order to save on characters, since it wasn't specified that the program had to terminate. :)
2. `"publicas{tvodmn(Srg[])h=0;w+ye.\"\\xO<?:} ".indexOf(c)<0?c:""`: Sadly, not a very elegant approach, but it gets the job done.  Manually list every character present in the source code as a `String` literal, then check whether the current `char c` occurs within it with `indexOf()`.  If the `indexOf()` call returns `-1`, it doesn't exist, and therefore we should print it.  The rest of it just uses the ternary operator to save on characters and space.

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Comment: @joeyrohan Sure, just added an explanation below it. :)

Comment: cool ;) nice stuff :)

Comment: You could put the ENTIRE ascii printable table in a comment and make a java programm that returns nothing. It'd beat yours :-)

Comment: I gave an answer with 124 characters ;p

Comment: You can do indexOf(++c) to remove the increment part of the loop entirely, shaving off a character.

Comment: @ICR True.  Nice catch.

Comment: 1) You seem to be missing space (0x20) from your list of exclusions.

Comment: 2) You can be slightly shorter by using if instead of the ternary because in this instance they're the same length, but you can remove ? and : from the string.

Comment: You could have told me that this is going to print every single Unicode character before I executed it in my terminal.

Comment: You can save a character by changing it to indexOf(++c) and removing the c++ inside the for loop

Answer (score 16):

### Perl, 49 characters

```
say grep/[^+-246\[-^aceghmprsy]/,map chr,041..126
```

This is an interesting challenge -- it's sort of the anti-quine, and I've managed to shorten the program a couple of times by *increasing* the range of characters that appear in it.

Answer (score 15):

### Ruby, <s>81</s> <s>78</s> <s>68</s> <s>66</s> <s>62</s> 57

```
(?!..?~).map{|a|$><<a if/[()ifmap{}|?!.~\/\\\[\]$><]/!~a}
```

Simply checks itself. Duplicate characters manually removed.

Thanks to Josh for saving 4 characters, and minitech for saving 5 characters!

Comment: Can't you put the if after the $><<x to save one of the end lines?

Comment: @Josh Yes. I will do that now.

Comment: You can take it to 58: `(?!..?~).map{|x|$><<x if/[()ifmap{}|x?!.~\/\\\[\]$><]/!~x}`

Comment: Ah, and with a better choice of variable name, 57: `(?!..?~).map{|a|$><<a if/[()ifmap{}|?!.~\/\\\[\]$><]/!~a}`

Comment: `$><<((32..126).map(&:chr)-IO.read(__FILE__).chars).join` 55 bytes using a different approach.

Comment: [47 bytes using grep instead of map](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v6AoM69EQUvDXlFPz75OUy@9KLVAQz86TlFDVytGV9fAPko3HiQGVFUXq6/5/z8A "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 15):

### Befunge (48)

```
<|::-1,+*88:<+3*87
6<@.**85
9>"()~&"/%$ |!#';=?}
```

Outputs: {zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^][ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA240

Comment: Holy cow! Nice work!

Answer (score 14):

Not very serious, but I had to give it a go:

### JSFuck (138152)

[(compiled source here)](http://wmmusic.nl/codexamples/printsitselfjsfuck.js)

Original source:

```
for(x=0x7e;x>0x19;x--){
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(x).replace(/[\[\]!\+\(\)]/ig, ''))
}
```

Prints all characters except ***()+[]!***

Comment: `(x)` <=> `[x][+[]]`, increases code size but makes the alphabet needed smaller.

Comment: I "compress" your JSF code https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/242835/88163 :D

Answer (score 12):

### GolfScript (<strike>18</strike> 16 chars)

```
"),@`^^32>#.~".~
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IiksQGBeXjMyPiMufiIufgoKLnB1dHMgMTI3LDMyPl4nIiksQGBeXjMyPiMufiIufideLA%3D%3D) with an extra line which does a correctness check and outputs the number of characters in error.

(I have various equivalent alternatives. `` @`^ `` can be replaced with `` \\` ``; `#` can be replaced with `` ` `` or `]`. The right combination can be used with Howard's trick to equal his score of 15 because backslashes don't need escaping in blocks the way they do in string literals: `` {),\`^32>].~}.~ ``. But Howard deserves the credit for that trick).

Comment: nice rule abuse :-) http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ImAnficoLCszMj5cXC0uIi5%2B

Comment: Fortunately ascii ends in `}~` - even better for code blocks, see my new answer ;-)

Answer (score 12):

## Brainfuck, 173

```
+++++[->++++++<]>>>++[------<+>]<++++>>----[----<+>]>-[-------<+>]>-[---<+>]<------->>-[---<+>]<+++++++++>>--[-----<+>]<+++++>>+[---------<++>]+++++++++++++[<[.+<]>[>]<-]\=,
```

Pretty long, I might try again later.

Comment: write a program that does nothing and add the rest od ascii to the source, worst case feels like 96 characters.

Answer (score 11):

### J (<s>52</s> 40)

Edit: Duh, forgot about `e.`

```
'''(-@.e#[)~95{32}a'(-.@e.#[)~95{.32}.a.
```

Old version:

```
(>@(*/@('(>@*/''&~:).#]32{95}a'&~:)&.>)#])95{.32}.a.
```

Other variant (same length but less output):

```
([#~*/"1@('([#~*/"1@''&:0)95{.32}a'&~:"0))95{.32}.a.
```

Comment: @JanDvorak: whoops typo

Comment: Darn it! I was hoping I could get low enough in Ruby to beat you and then you drop it all the way to 40. :P

Comment: The new one looks much more quiney.

Comment: @Doorknob: I have one in APL that's only 24 characters but it has non-ASCII characters in it.

Comment: Yeah, I did the ASCII thing to avoid languages like APL.

Comment: @marinus I have one in J that's 24 characters.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 3 - <del>68</del> 61

```
x=r"print(*set(map(chr,range(32,127)))-set(x+'=\"'))"
exec(x)
```

... thanks to @WolframH for the improvements.

Comment: I think you can put `exec(x)` in a new line and save the `;` in `x`. Also, in Python 3, you can use `x=r"print(*set(map(chr,range(32,127)))-set(x+'=\"'))"\nexec(x)` for 61 chars (prints multiple spaces, which is allowed).

Comment: Massively late, I know, but with some new Python 3 tricks you can take it down to 55 chars: `x=r"print(*{*map(chr,range(32,127))}-{*x})#=\""\nexec(x)`.

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell: 96

Must be saved and run as a script.

```
diff([char[]](gc $MyInvocation.InvocationName))([char[]](32..126))-Pa|?{$_.SideIndicator-eq'=>'}
```

`diff` is a built-in alias for `Compare-Object`.

`gc` is a built-in alias for `Get-Content`.

`$MyInvocation.InvocationName` gets the full path to the script being executed.

`32..126` is the decimal equivalent for `0x20..0x7e`, and so creates an array of the decimal ASCII codes we're looking for.

`[char[]]` takes the contents of the next object and puts them into an array, breaking them up and converting them into ASCII characters. So, we now have two arrays of ASCII characters - one pulled from this script, the other defined by the challenge criteria.

`-Pa` sets `Compare-Object` to "Passthru" format, so only the items which are found different between the inputs are output at the console - indicators of which items were in which input are still stored in the object's data, but are not displayed.

`|?{$_.SideIndicator-eq'=>'}` pipes `Compare-Object`'s output to `Where-Object`, which filters it down to only the items which are exclusive to the second input.

Comment: Sane and instructive.

Answer (score 7):

## **Java - 126 characters**

minimized:

```
class hjq{public static void main(String...w){for(char z='"'|0;++z!='a';)if("'()+.0;=OS".indexOf(z)==~0)System.out.print(z);}}
```

unminimized:

```
class hjq {
    public static void main(String... w) { 
        for (char z = '"'|0; ++z != 'a';) {
            if ("'()+.0;=OS".indexOf(z) == ~0) {
                System.out.print(z);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is an interesting problem, because individual tokens might benefit from their longer form because it re-uses characters. For example, normally `String[]` would be shorter, but `String...` removes the need for the square brackets in the conditional string.

I found the trick was to try and use characters at the beginning and end of the range so you can exclude them from the output simply by altering your loop start and end.

For Java, a key character to exclude is `"`, because having that in the string requires escaping it, which adds `\` to your program, which needs to go in the string, which adds `\\`. By removing `"` from your conditional string you remove 4 characters. This can be achieved by making sure you use and `!` and starting your loop from `#`.

All the lowercase letters appear near the end of the range, with only `{`, `|`, `}` and `~` coming after them. Because of Java's verbosity, most of the lowercase letters are used just for the boilerplate. Likewise, `{` and `}` are trivial for a Java program, because the boilerplate requires them.

`|` can be used if you have an or condition, but I couldn't find a way to take advantage of one that leads to a shorter program than just using `|` as a bitwise operator. The `|0` makes me feel a little dirty, because it's the only part that's a nop just to get the character in there.

`~0` yields `-1`, which is handy because that's what we need to check for with `indexOf`. Combining this with using `!=` for the loop conditional eliminates the `<` character altogether, which means it doesn't need to go inside the conditional string.

Answer (score 6):

**Javascript, 92**

```
(function f(){for(i=32;126>i++;)!~(""+f).indexOf(c=String.fromCharCode(i))&&console.log(c)})()
```

Comment: Is this a fair solution?   

    alert(' !"#$%^*+/-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`bcdfghijkmnopqsuvwxyz{|}~')

Comes in at 95 chars and is dumb as hell. :p

Comment: @tristin :P yeah javascript is a bit verbose when it comes to charcode to string. And isn't it output every character your program dosn't have. The text your alerting is in your program as well :)

Comment: Haha, oops. Oh well.

Answer (score 6):

## [BitShift](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BitShift), 1038 bytes

BitShift is a language which only supports `0` and `1` as syntax. I figured it would be easy to print all other characters, but since it doesn't really support looping it still ended up a massive 1038 bytes.
However, I believe it's not really possible to go any smaller than this..

```
101001100101011011010100110111010100100101011001101111010100100101011001000101011011010100101100110110101001001010110010001010110110101000001101010010010101100100010101101101010000010000011001010110110101000010000101011011010100110111010100100101011111100101011011010100110111010100100101011001101111010100100101011001000101011011010100000000011010100100101011001000101011011010100110010000101011011010100110111010100100101011001101001101010010010101100100010101101101010011001000010101101101010011011101010010010101111011111110010101101101010011011101010010010101100101100101011011010100010001010110110101001000010101101101010011011101010010010101110111110010101101101010011011101010010010101111111100101011011010100110111010100100101011111011110101001001010110010001010110110101001000100000101011011010100110111010100100101011111010011010100100101011001000101011011010100100000101011011010100110111010100100101011001101111010100100101011001000101011011010100010000010101101101010011011101010010010101101001101101010010010101101001101010
```

Prints

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Try it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10914578/Bitshift.html)

Answer (score 5):

### Python 2, 69

```python
for x in range(38):print chr(x+59)#!"$%&'*,-./012467bdjklmqsuvwyz{|}~
```

I use the longest (that I'm able to find) sequence of continuous chars I can print out and add the others as a comment after the code.

Comment: I'm not going to upvote anything that has a comment

Comment: My answer should show the worst possible way to solve this task. (Use the comment loophole).

Comment: ok... except for that polyglot that is nothing _but_ a comment.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn However, as it's the longest code that works, it won't win the contest. :P

Comment: @JoeZ. it wins by a wide margin if you divide by the number of languages it works in

Comment: It's no longer even the longest code, so my comment no longer applies.

Answer (score 5):

### sh (47)

```sh
tr</dev/urandom -cd \[:print:]|tr -d "`cat $0`"
```

Uses the self-referential approach. Assumes `/dev/urandom` will eventually output every octet at least once.  Doesn't terminate.

If we assume that `man` is installed, we could instead make use of the `ascii(7)` manpage (and thus have a terminating program) (**44** chars, thanks @fennec).

```sh
man ascii|tr -cd \[:print:]|tr -d "`cat $0`"
```

Comment: Could you use another file, possibly with a shorter name, that's essentially guaranteed to have all possible octets? and might even terminate? I'm thinking like /dev/memory or something.

Comment: @fennec if we assume that `man` and `zsh` are installed, `man zshall` seems to fit the criteria. I could add that as a variation.

Comment: `man ascii` could save you another letter, I think.

Comment: Which `tr` are you using?  GNU `tr` treats the `-` in "`cat $0`" as a range operator, which breaks the output.

Comment: BTW, if the `ascii` program is installed, you could use that in place of `man ascii`.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, <s>133</s> <s>123</s> <s>114</s> 110 bytes

```
++++++++++++++++[->++++++>++>+++>++++>++<<<<<]>-->>->->+[---<.+.+<.+<.+<.+.+.+>>>>]++[-<.+.+.+<.+>>]<+.<+.<++.
```

A bit of more tinkering with a former solution (before I realized the below was smaller - allthough this was before I did some heavy optimization). This works by storing 4 sets of ascii numbers and print them with some tricky looping, and then give the missing characters afterwards (i.e. ones that are between invalid ascii numbers).

Original submission

```
>>+++++++++++[<+<+>>->++>+++<<]<++>>++++++>>+++++[-<<<++++++>>>]<<<+<<[->>+.<<]>>++.++<[->+.<]>++.+>[-<+.>]<++.+>>[-<<+.>>]
```

It does the following:

- Create 4 registers containing 11. 13, 28, 33
- Create a 5th with the value 31 to start the printing
- Print ascii 32-42 (11)
- Print ascii 44
- Print ascii 47-59 (13)
- Print ascii 61
- Print ascii 63-90 (28)
- Print ascii 92
- Print ascii 94-126 (33)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

I don't think I saw any Vyxal on here! Prints all printable ASCII with kQ and filters chars out with F

```
kQ`\kQF\``F
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCJrUWBcXGtRRlxcYGBGIiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Thank you! Happy to be here!

Comment: Welcome to the vyxal crew :p

Comment: @lyxal Good documentation, great balance between readability and conciseness. What's not to love??

Answer (score 4):

Definitely the longest solution here, but coding in Lino is always fun:

## [L.in.oleum](http://anynowhere.com/bb/layout/html/frameset.html) - <del>655</del> 523 characters

```
"libraries"/arch/cpu/base;/hmi/conout;/data/bytes;/data/string/t2s;/data/heap;/data/heap/connect/mgrab;"stockfile"a;"directors"displaystatus=engage;"injection"c=524;b<-bytes.bytesizeconvert:c;b<-heap.alloc:b;a<-heap.alloc:c;[filecommand]=readfile;[filename]=stockfile;[fileposition]=0;[fileblocksize]=c;[fileblockpointer]=b;arch.fileread;[string.psource]=b;[string.ptarget]=a;string.t2s;b<-heap.alloc:7fh;c=32;d=b;"f"[d_32]=c;+c;+d;?c<7fh>f;"w"d=[a];+a;?d=0>y;?d<32>w;?d>7eh>w;e=b;e+d;[e]=33;^w;"y"b+32;"v"conout.say:b;bye;
```

No comments, just reads the source compiled into binary. Save as `a.txt` or it won't compile!

Comment: Nope, the JSFuck one is longer.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell (70)

```haskell
import Data.List
main=putStrLn$[' '..'~']\\" \\\"$'.=DLS[]aimnoprstu~"
```

The boring duplicate-characters-in-program-in-a-string, subtract-from-universal-set solution.  Far from a codegolf winner, though it's surprisingly legible for its length.

(Now with list subtraction instead of `filter`/`notWith`.)

Comment: you can change `import Data.List` to `import List`

Comment: .@proudhaskeller huh, really? It doesn't seem to work when I try it with `runhaskell`: "Could not find module ‘List’". I noticed I'd miscount the number of characters though, so I corrected it.

Comment: well, that's weird, try it with ghc or ghci? It works for me

Comment: @proudhaskeller nope, can't get it to work. This is with GHC 7.8.3.

Answer (score 4):

## Java - 111 Bytes

I know I'm 4 years too late, but I just found this question.

```
void SPARE_VOMIT(){System.out.print(0!=('^'>>8|3&6%2<<~7*4)?"$#/^@\bc[]":'`'-5+"lnbfghjkqwxyz".toUpperCase());}
```

I tried to put as few characters in the ignored String as possible.

Ungolfed:

```
void SPARE_VOMIT(){                                   // vomit out all the spare characters
    System.out.print(0 != ('^'>>8|3&6%2<<~7*4) ?             // Both sides here = 0
                     "$#/^@\bc[]"              :             // The shame string...
                     '`'-5 + "lnbfghjkqwxyz".toUpperCase()); // Print 91 and caps.
}
```

Comment: SPARE_VOMIT... heh... +1

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135601/76162)</sup>

```
" 'r:{-}30{l4-*?.~~:9e*=?;:l2=?o1+}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0lBvciqWrfW2KA6x0RXy16vrs7KMlXL1t7aKsfI1j7fULv2/38A)

Outputs `` !#$%&(),/5678<>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdfghijkmnpqstuvwxyz| ``

#### How It Works:

```
"   Wrapping string literal, adding the source code to the stack.
    This adds a space at the start to initialise the counter
  '  Runs another string literal over the whole code
     This means both " and ' are added to the stack
   r:  Get the counter from the bottom of the stack and duplicate it
     {-}  Get the bottom of the stack and check if it is equal to the counter. Push the check to the bottom of the stack
        30  Add 3, 0 to the stack for later
          {l4-*  Get the equality check from the bottom of the stack and OR it with whether the stack is empty of values to check against
               ?.  If the character is equal or the stack is empty, continue. 
                   Else set the instruction pointer to 3,0 to check against the next character
                 ~~  Pop the excess 3,0
                   :9e*=?;  Check if the counter is equal to the 126, the last character, and end if so.
                          :l2=?o  If the stack is empty of values to check (ie the character is not in the code), print it.
                                1+}  Add one to the counter and, because ><> is toroidal, loop back to the beginning
```

Comment: [Crossed out 4 is still 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=crossed+out+4+is+still+4+%3B%28)

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 90 bytes

```
++++[->+++>++++++++<<]>-[->.>+<+<]>+.+++>++[-<.<++>+>]<+.++<++[->.>+<+<]>+.++>+++++[-<.+>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fGwiide2AJAiDgY1NrJ0uUEzPTttGG8jW1oPIRuva6NmAWHaxNiAxG7BOZFUQI0DqgGr@/wcA)

**Tape Layout:**

*`[Initial Count Cell] , [Counter Cell One] , [Ascii Cell] , [Counter Cell Two]`*

**Explanation:**

```
++++[->+++>++++++++<<]>-      # sets counter cell one to 11 and ascii cell to 32
[->.>+<+<]                    # prints ascii 32-42 and creates counter cell two
>+.+++>++                     # prints ascii 44 and sets counter cell two to 13
[-<.<++>+>]                   # prints ascii 47-59 and resets counter cell one
<+.++<++                      # prints ascii 61 and sets counter cell one to 28
[->.>+<+<]                    # prints ascii 63-90 and resets counter cell two
>+.++>+++++                   # prints ascii 92 and sets counter cell two to 33
[-<.+>]                       # prints remaining ascii characters
```

**Output:**

```
 !"#$%&'()*,/0123456789:;=?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 72 bytes

```r
cat(intToUtf8(setdiff(32:126,utf8ToInt("\\\"(),12368:ITUacdefinostu"))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDgAREADAv6hWokEi4gd6Oo1gEw3JWe/fM@V8zK0SzEVpZ0IPZ1CfiGBN0Map@y7tuAhEKUWAVNpY50NMubY@cK596Ar5MP8)

With correction from @JayCe

Comment: nicely done! Beats out the default polyglot by a fair margin!

Comment: I think you're missing `\\ ` in the string which costs 2 bytes :( Otherwise I tried to golf it further but couldn't - clever use of `setdiff` !

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcgxDgAREADAr9ypVqJBiPiBngcINtGQnPV@Z8r5zimZoA@KMxE6WI1qRwRtvFRW7HtxhkHAnhe4kEob63yIKZfasI@5aDN@nfMD "R – Try It Online")  by starting at 35, which avoids the `\\\"` issue.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), <s>91</s> 86 bytes

```
{POW(77,7)} /*-#!"$%&'9:;<=>?@ABCDFGHIJKLMNQRSTUVXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v@/OsA/XMPcXMdcs1ZBX0tXWVFJRVVN3dLK2sbWzt7B0cnZxc3dw9PL28fXLzAoOCQ0LCIyKjomNi4@ITEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orKqpu7/fwA)

Prints `1.604852E+13`

The only thing Ink can really *do* to a string is print it - if you want to do actual string processing, you're meant to hook into external code. This means almost all characters will have to occur in our code, since we generally have no way to print the ones that don't. That means we can basically treat the first occurrence of each character as being free, and see how much stuff we can generate with as few *repeated* characters as possible.

One thing Ink *can* do is math. We can generate and print a number. With only two repeated characters, the expression `{POW(77,7)}` becomes `1.604852E+13`, which has eleven distinct characters, none of which are used in the expression.

At this point, there isn't much more we could generate. We need `7` in our code, and while we might be able to generate a `-`, we'd need another set of `{}` to do more math, so that would really be a net negative. So we begin a multi-line comment using `/*` (because Ink doesn't care if we ever close those) and shove all the rest of the characters we aren't using in there.

- `-5 bytes` by creating a larger floating-point number using `POW` instead of `FLOAT`, which then also includes `E` and `+` and has fewer repeated characters

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 68 <del>83</del> <del>88</del> (but it actually reads the file)

No comments, no hacks, it just opens itself, and checks the contents. Includes the set logic from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12375).

```python
print"".join(set(map(chr,range(32,127)))-set(open(__file__).read()))
```

Changed to print the output and not an array.

Comment: Outputs the following characters which are in the program: ` 127[]acdefrtx`

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus I've corrected that, and have met your score!

Comment: These are definitely not ASCII characters. ASCII below 32 only contains control codes (Backspace, Bell, etc.), whitespace (CR, LF, tab), and the null char.

Comment: @Felix These are from [Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_437) (which starts at U+2639, I believe)

Comment: @FelixDombek Windows has lied to me again, removed the last bit.

Comment: You can get this down to 62 chars in python3 using @WolframH 's idea: `print(*set(map(chr,range(32,127)))-set(open(__file__).read()))`. Longer by 1 character than the other answer, but more pythonic in my opinion

Comment: Python 3 can actually get down to [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ6taKzexQCM5o0inKDEvPVXD2EjH0MhcU7NWt1orvyA1T8NAU68oNTFFQ7NWpzi1wFZdXfP/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## J - 21

```
(u:32+i.97)-.1!:1<":5
```

write this to a file called `5` in the current directory. Then load execute the script with `0!:1<'5'`

Or 25 without the file trick:

```
(-.~".)'(":u:32+i.0-~95)'
```

Comment: Source code contains `'`, which isn't removed from the output.

Answer (score 3):

**Clojure (<del>142, 106</del>, 103)**

```
(defn -main[](let[c"(fn[l](pr(reduce disj(set(map char(range 32 126)))l)));-\\\"o"]((load-string c)c)))
```

formatted:

```
(defn -main []
  (let [c "(fn[l](pr(reduce disj(set(map char(range 32 126)))l)));-\\\"o"]
    ((load-string c) c)))
```

Think this does it, may need some tweaks.
output:

```
#{@ ` ! A B b # C $ D % E & F ' G H I * J + K k , L M . N / O 0 P Q q R S 4 T 5 U V v 7 W w 8 X x 9 Y y : Z z { < | = } > ^ ? _}
```

runs the string, which is evaluateable clojure code, on itself.  String has some comments at the end to get the characters used outside of the string (main method, etc)

Answer (score 3):

### Bash (pure), <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 88 bytes

```
eval "a=$'$(printf '\\x%x' {32..127})'"
while read -rn1 c;do a=${a/"$c"};done<$0
echo $a
```

#### Example

```
cat > foo.sh # now paste and C-d
bash foo.sh  # !#&*+,45689:>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`bgjkmqsuyz|~
wc -c foo.sh # 93 (including end-of-line \n)
```

#### Explanation

- The `eval` thing: construct a string that looks like `\x20\x21...\x7f`, and use bash&ksh's c-style-quote `$'c-escape-str'` to wrap it, in order to escape it into some real list-of-chars.
- Then we use a while loop to read chars one-by-one, and use the 'replace first occurance' `${var/pat}` to kill corresponding chars in `$a`.
  Note that we didn't set `IFS` properly, and `read` by default will consume `\x20`, `\n` and `\t`. The `\x20` part will be handled later.
- Finally we abuse IFS again so it can eat the space.

The output is in ASCII char order.

This very literal (for code golfs at least) one actually ended up smaller than what I expected it to be. Otherwise I will be thinking about `# !&*+abc....`

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 61 bytes

#### Code:

```
~:5+1-777(B1D1+7)6+33077777(D3B3@6-7)0&2 !"#$%'*,./489;<=>?AC
```

#### Unique characters in program:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCD~
```

#### Output:

```
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 83 bytes

```
00000000: 2b2b 7036 092e 452c 453b 3b78 6f2c 4523  ++p6..E,E;;xo,E#
00000010: 2323 2323 2323 2323 2323 2323 2323 2329  ###############)
00000020: 2929 2929 2929 2929 307e 7620 2122 2425  ))))))))0~v !"$%
00000030: 2627 282a 2d2f 3132 3334 3537 3839 3a3c  &'(*-/12345789:<
00000040: 3d3e 3f40 4142 4344 7172 7374 7577 797a  =>?@ABCDqrstuwyz
00000050: 7b7c 7d                                  {|}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hczJTsNAEATQO19REAiEhDDTNeO2EwgQ8Id45YIU9iUsv27GMBe4pA6lbqn01qm5Xt20XWdiZpBSSqhhApNJA@elCsUSLDVF0v68QmA8vk2m03ySz@evq0k@2PoVbG8wDDZWBgz@ZhQN6Y0sDP4VjTbQRAzEikCceGAUY76esb2zuxcN9kYiCkmlgNTSgpYCkg70VDBlIAtWwHD/4PDo2Aqd1zSbnUTDBYM1G7B1Bs46gaNzUKsCpYbLq0IzLYDTxdn5xfLy6u7@4fHp5W0dDR8MLbWC1tiY94/PrvsG)

Printable characters aren't *too* useful in z80, but we can write this:

```
   dec hl
   dec hl
   ld (hl),b
   ld (hl),9
   ld l,'E'
   inc l
   ld b,l

   dec sp      ; $0009 starts here
   dec sp
   ld a,b
   ld l,a
   inc l
   ld b,l
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   inc hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   add hl,hl
   jr nc, $+2+'~'
   halt
   db " !\"$%&'(*-/12345789:<=>?@ABCDqrstuwyz{|}"
```

The idea is to print characters from `'F'` to `'n'`, and put all the remaining characters in the code (the "garbage" string at the end).

The preamble writes `09` (tab) to `$fffe`, so that we can point SP there to jump to `$0009` after putchar. The `ld (hl), b` achieves nothing; I just get rid of `'p'` there.

`L` is initialized to `'E'+1`, and counts up until `(HL+17) << 9` overflows (sets the carry), which is when `L` is 111 = `'o'`, the first character we don't want to print.

If the carry is *not* set, we jump over a halt instruction and the garbage string, into thousands of NOPs, the PC eventually running into `putchar = $8000` and returning to `$0009`.

See [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166951/3852) for some more info on how this code prints characters in the first place.

Comment: nvm I saw that the code had to be printable as well.

Answer (score 3):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), <s>70</s> <s>55</s> 51 bytes

```
{iii}i{icicicicicic}dd{ci}iicicicici{ic}dd{ci}iciic
```

Because, y'know, I'm hilarious and original.

*Saved 15 bytes by repeating a few characters*
*Saved 4 more by simplifying both instances of*  `d{ic}i` *to* `{ci}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0lNTEnLLM7Q/f@/OjMzszazOjMZAWtTUqqTgYJwkWqEWDJQ9P9/AA)

**Previous Version (55 bytes):**

```
{iii}i{icicicicicic}ddd{ic}iiicicicici{ic}ddd{ic}iiciic
```

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 95 bytes

```
[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~]
```

The way this works is pretty simple, any decent Brainfuck interpreter will ignore  the code between the brackets appearing at the start of source file, therefore creating a comment.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 20 bytes

```
PARM`[\\APRM\`\]\[]`
```

Uses the predefined printable ASCII variable, and regexes out the letters in the code.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/wDHINyE6JsYxIMg3JiEmNiY6NuH/fwA)

Comment: Added that into the Regex.

Answer (score 2):

## Q, 44

```
-1"c"$til[128]except"i"$"-1\"c$til[28]exp;";
```

.

```
q)-1"c"$til[128]except"i"$"-1\"c$til[28]exp;";
345679:<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abdfghjkmnoqrsuvwyz{|}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Bash internals only, 133 bytes

```
w=printf
while IFS= read -r -n1 r;do i[$($w %d \'$r)]=1;done<$0
for r in {33..126};do [[ 1 -ne ${i[$r]} ]]&& $w \\$($w "%o" $r);done
```

Save and run with `bash <filename>`

#### Explanation

1. Make `printf` shorter.
2. For each char `r` read from `$0` (i.e. the script itself), set `i[ord(r)]` to 1.
3. For each number `r` in `range(33, 127)`, if `i[r]` is not `1`, `printf` the char corresponding to the number `r`. The `$w \\$($w "%o" $r)` part is where the number-to-char magic is: convert the number to OCT, and then prepend a backslash, and finally feed to `printf` to really print it.

The output is in ASCII order.

Comment: Actually I count 132. You can spare a few more characters: http://pastebin.com/G8YDBzJj – 113 characters.

Comment: This would get my upvote with some explanation about how it works.

Answer (score 2):

**C++ 143**

```cpp
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
char c[256],d,e=32;int main(){for(std::fstream i(__FILE__);i>>d;)c[d]++;for(;++e<127;)c[e]||std::cout<<e;}
```

**Alternative version using macros - 155**

```cpp
#include"iostream"
#define d int main(){while(s,*s)l[*s++]++;for(e=35;++e<127;)!l[e]&&std::cout<<e;}
#define t(a)#a
#define f(a)t(a)
char*s=f(d),l[257],e;d
```

**And a version without 'reflection' (examining own source) - 139**

```cpp
#include"iostream"
char h['~'],*a="'()*+,:;<=[]acdefhilmnorstu{}",i='#';int main(){for(;*a;)h[*a++]++;for(;++i<'~';)if(!h[i])std::cout<<i;}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, with coreutils, 80

```
p=printf
for o in {32..126};{
c=`$p $($p "\%o" $o)`
grep -qF "$c" $0||$p "$c"
}
```

Output is:

```
!#&'}+,/45789:<>}@ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_abhjklmsuvwxyz~
```

Comment: Never heard about this `for v in something; COMPOUND_CMD` syntax. Great…

Comment: Just a `grep` replacement, but 5-bytes longer: `[[ $(<$0) = *"$c"* ]]`

Comment: only 3 bytes longer now: remove the double quotes

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 62

```
from string import*;print set(printable)-set(open("p").read())
```

Code must be saved in a file called `p`.

Lowest python solution so far ;D

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 75 bytes

```
[char[]](32..39+42+44+45+47+58..90+92+94..96+98+100..103+105..113+115..126)
```

A different approach than the [other PowerShell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15374/42963). Here, we manually build a list of ASCII values `(...)` that aren't in the source code, then cast that as a char-array `[char[]]`. PowerShell will by default write out values alone on a line like this, so we get printing for free.

Characters used in code: `()+.0123456789[]achr`

Answer (score 2):

### Marbelous, 111 bytes

```
@0
--7E
<XE\
../\@0
:E\
}0}0
&0&1
{0{>
}0
-F
-E
-5
-4
>0
-7
>D
-F
>0
-2
>0
-2
>0
-3
>3
-2
-6
-8
-9
>0
&0&1
\/\/
```

Main board loops from 0x7E down to 0x20, E\ function rejects values by decrementing and comparing to small numbers (Marbelous' built in < and > operators only work on the range 0-35).

Answer (score 2):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <s>83</s> 79 bytes

```
120d115 108 100 93 91 80 62[d1-d43<:]ds:x[l.dP]s;34s.[dl.!=;s,l.1+ds.127>/]ds/x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcotGoAgDADQq8yszg1Q@VHPYOcjuUhb4fZIeO3J1zsbEuYdmPxAECwEBk9wmCy8irNXLKKx5YryFk3WKWapON1Jl4o8iyKb89nG2lrvPw)

Prints `` "#$%&'()*?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`abcefghijkmnopqrtuvwyz{|}~ ``

The lazy answer of commenting out the entire printable range (and printing nothing) would be 95 bytes, so while this may be suboptimal, I'm pretty pleased.

`120d115 108 100 93 91 80 62[d1-d43<:]ds:x` puts all the values on the stack that we need to ignore. Decimal is seemingly the ideal base for this, particularly when I factor in the additional characters that would be needed to change the input base. The first few values I have to enter in manually, but I use all the characters from 43-62, so I can generate those in a loop. I don't need to use a few of these characters, but it saves bytes to run through the ones that I don't need, so I named my registers/macros `:`, `.`, `,`, `;`, and `/` for the sake of using those characters.

`[l.dP]s;` is the macro that will print the character if it's not in the list. `34s.` is the counter - since I use characters 32 and 33, I just start at 34. `[dl.!=;s,l.1+ds.127>/]ds/x` is a pretty straightforward macro, just load the counter, `.`, see if it's in the list, run `;` if so, increment, and loop until we're out of printable range.

Golfed off four bytes because I was accidentally omitting `p` (this also made my answer invalid!). I must have at one point used both `P` and `p` to print, or thought I would have to.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 bytes

```
Vp.."-"Vp-"-
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Vp..%22-%22Vp-%22-&i=&a=1)

Added for completeness.

`Vp` in Stax is the set of all printable ASCII characters, `.."` is the two character string literal (of `."`) in Stax.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 33 bytes

```
157 255B'QJ.V"157 2B'QJ.VSK"SK'"K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0NRcwcjU1Ek90EsvTAnMg7CDvZWCvdWVvP//BwA)

---

Pushes `žQ` by converting 157 into base 255.

Executes `žQ` with `.V` which pushes the printable ASCII character set (32-128).

Then remove all characters in the source code using `K`.

Comment: I have the feeling the program string can somehow be combined with a `D.VsSK` but I'm unable to find a way to accomplish it..:( That `J` screws things up so much.. +1 though, nice answer.

Comment: Ok, found something! :) [`"YSK157 255B'QJ.V"VY.VYSK'"K` **28 bytes**](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fKTLY29DUXMHI1NRJPdBLL0wpLFIvDCioruT9/z8A) `"YSK157 255B'QJ.V"` is the string. This is popped and saved in variable `Y`, after which it's pushed again, and executed with `.V` (the `YSK` are no-ops; and the `157 255B'QJ.V` is still the same as in your answer). Then the characters of this string `Y` are removed with `YSK`, and finally the double quote is removed (again, same as in your answer) with `'"K`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen your 28 can easily be 25 [by merging the two `YSK`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fydDUXMHI1NRJPdBLLywy2FspLFIvTF3J@/9/AA). Using modern 05AB1E, I can get 24 with [`"8!55+257B.V3.$YSK"VY.V`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fQclC0dRU28jU3EkvzFhPJTLYWyksUi/s/38A).

Answer (score 2):

## [Memory GAP](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/memory-GAP), 3104 bytes

```
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
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VZLrhwxCDxRJLDBwHEwmKyeEmWX00@YE/Si1Zos3q7VmHJB8fHX@fr15@@Pn/779RLaKnMKMQ2ApJyzFILWmhl8uGTngi28h6XYXgt8KNs0DvRBcKzw6CHYW@wowIYIozl1QhRNOiFa/QurNh6mSOVDDjb60Pjf/SVOqcskZRaRGG4J4UVjrXWW7YFewVSbNJFnoCHgYi3y4aRX@HftbNR6zT0VnHDaOvlWzlsfmK3pXf2etl/pc9d@936SHYdDqFitSJfkTpZj4daJ16v8Ps3/Sv@78d@Nry/DdraAwr1cJ8Y0O2OZSLcQXuHXoBiBjZAwxSSWCpk2UqIxrkv@XtBInOVJnF6JFWMm45hLeRY4ZmWsZtCf5IvArMQD4xyd3/Pxs/19t36e7q@791/V5@P9dVH/d/vv7v50lTwbMLh42lk7vbGGhZ56Z6j5DEFvTXIHvaMH2WdLDsO2sHLT0ISxAlD7RJsNO8hV1s7jHUxDI7Inkg1sgtgzvlmfUMDL/f7h@vyeT8/Op9vvBxy0A9zm5BhSoKtbavsAcTIcn95/V/X/ev0D)

Expanded:

```
74b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a240e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4
34ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e
54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf47cef8a734855777c2a9d0caf42666e69
b21afc54fb48d153c19101658f4a2a480e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf40e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf40e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4594f803b380a41396ed63dca39503542
f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a240e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf40e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf40e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf40e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4
34ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a092433234ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a092433234ec78fcc91ffb1e
54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a0924332
47bce5c74f589f4867dbd57e9ca9f808f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a2434ec78fcc91ffb1e
54cd85e4a092433234ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4
594f803b380a41396ed63dca395035420e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e
54cd85e4a0924332f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a2434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a0924332
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a24f24c2c15b9d03797
c6874986a8d1951634ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a0924332faf05c15dfad45dafd1fc23d51236853
f0a1dfdc675b0a14a64099f7ac1cee8374b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5f7bd60b75b29d79b
660a2859395c1a240e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a0924332
0e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4
0e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a092433234ec78fcc91ffb1e
54cd85e4a09243320cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a24
34ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4594f803b380a4139
6ed63dca39503542f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a2434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a0924332
faf05c15dfad45dafd1fc23d5123685334ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320cc175b9c0f1b6a8
31c399e269772661f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a24f0a1dfdc675b0a14a64099f7ac1cee83
f24c2c15b9d03797c6874986a8d1951634ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243327cef8a734855777c
2a9d0caf42666e69b21afc54fb48d153c19101658f4a2a48a87deb01c5f539e6bda34829c8ef2368
c68271a63ddbc431c307beb7d2918275852438d026c018c4307b916406f98c6274985f5115ad1492
12a917dbef8ec801b21afc54fb48d153c19101658f4a2a480cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a2434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf474b87337454200d4d33f80c4663dc5e5f7bd60b75b29d79b660a2859395c1a24
0e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4
34ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf40e9f1e8e40bb79e8
00b0cc9433830cf434ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243320e9f1e8e40bb79e800b0cc9433830cf4
34ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a09243324124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912f7bd60b75b29d79b
660a2859395c1a24f24c2c15b9d03797c6874986a8d1951634ec78fcc91ffb1e54cd85e4a0924332
faf05c15dfad45dafd1fc23d5123685374985f5115ad149212a917dbef8ec801
```

### Explanation

Memory GAP's instructions are md5 hashes of their *actual* instructions. Using `;` as a delimiter, this is the "original" program:

```
;
aaaa;size;dup;add;dup;add;dup;add;


dup;open;pop;
dup;

dup;
dup;
aaaaa;size;dup;dup;dup;dup;add;add;add;dup;add;aaa;size;add;add;dup;aaaaa;dup;add;size;add;a;size;neg;add;
btwn;

swap;
aaaa;size;dup;add;dup;add;dup;add;dup;dup;add;add;a;size;add;dup;aaaaa;size;add;btwn;
add;

a;size;swap;neg;add;
open;
pop;char;out;nil;shut;pop;

a;size;add;
dup;
aaaa;size;dup;add;dup;add;dup;add;
dup;dup;add;dup;add;aa;size;neg;add;btwn;
shut;
```

This simply iterates over the range between 32 and 126, and prints it if and only if it does not fall between `'0'` and `'9'` or `'a'` and `'f'`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 43 bytes

```perl6
<say |keys (" "..<~>) (-).comb#EVAL>~~.EVAL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9@mOLFSoSY7tbJYQUNJQUlPz6bOTlNBQ1dTLzk/N0nZNczRx66uTg9E//8PAA)

Uses the standard Perl6 quine format.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 41 bytes

```
"lops!;=`][' "s'"ll[p'~=[;]p~![!lo]pl`sl]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18pJ7@gWNHaNiE2Wl1BqVhdKScnukC9zjbaOragTjFaMSc/tiAnoTgn9v9/AA)

This one just pushes all the unique characters used in the code (minus `~` to the stack, along with `"`) then iterates from the codepoint for   (space) checking to see if that codepoint is on the stack.  Any codepoint that isn't found is printed.

```
"lops!;=`][' "                            - loads all the used chars to the stack
              s                           - save ` ` (space) to backup cell
               '"                         - add `"` to the stack too 
                 ll                       - load the curr codepoint twice
                   [p                  l] - infinite loop
                     '~=[;]p              - if the code point is `~` exit
                            ~              - search stack for curr codepoint
                             !             - negate results boolean
                              [!  ]p       - if/then, true if not found
                                lo         - restore curr codepoint and print
                                    l`s    - restore curr codepoint and increment
```

Output is:
`#$%&()*+,-./0123456789<>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_abcdefghijkmnqrtuvwxyz{|}`

Answer (score 2):

## [JSFuck](https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck) 11863

This answer is a compressed version of [this code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12734/88163)

```js
for(x=0x7e;x>0x19;x--){console.log(String.fromCharCode(x).replace(/[\[\]!\+\(\)]/ig,''))}
```

here is the full working JSFuck version of this code

```js
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]])+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+((![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+[+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])[(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]((!![]+[])[+[]])[([][(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]](([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+![]+(![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])()[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((![]+[+[]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])+[])[+!+[]])+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]])())
```

Comment: Characters other than `]` and `-` don't need to be escaped inside character groups.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (50)

```
puts (?#..?~).to_a.join.tr"()?!#.,~_aijnoprstu",""
```

Outputs:

```
$%&'*+-/0123456789:;<=>@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^`bcdefghklmqvwxyz{|}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 94

```
print !"#$%&'90*+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[/\]^_`abcdefghjklmoqsuvwxyz{|}
```

Comment: The "do nothing" solution was [already posted](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12370/7110).

Comment: @JoeZ. I've changed it to do something

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 2.1.0

### <del>206</del> 204 characters

```
chars_in_source = File.read("self.rb").chars.uniq.map(&:ord)
printable_ascii = (20..126).to_a
not_in_source = printable_ascii.reject { |c| chars_in_source.include?(c) }

puts not_in_source.map(&:chr).join
```

And the output is:

```
#$%'*+,-/345789;<>@ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^`gkvwxyz~
```

Not the shortest here (in fact, it might be the longest). But that's the great thing about this: it got me to go try something I'd never done before.

Comment: `VariableNamesGreaterThanOneCharacterLongException on line 1`

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>88 81 78</strike> 77 bytes

### actually reads the file

I tried to do it the 'clean' (as in 'easy to read') way, turned out quite nice, although i'm still new to python and probably this can be shortened as well.

file named 'a' is the file executed.

```
from string import*
for c in printable:
    if c not in open('a').read():print c
```

And it prints out all the ASCII characters not found in source file. I know this was supposed to be a clever hack (as in all those which contain all the ascii set or addresses, or use an error), but I wanted to do explicitly what was asked :]

Anyone has a suggestion how to make it even shorter while still going in this direction?

[edit] trimmed one more char, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Timtech's [tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17685) makes possible to reduce 1 more character.

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript 78 chars

```
bghjklm()seuABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZvwyz!@#$%^&*1234567890{}[]-=_+\;"'.,<>/?
```

Outputs:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Not the shortest code, but threw a try for fun. Notice the colon (`:`) and space () are covered in Output also.

Feedback appreciated.

Comment: And I just notice now that @xem has already done something similar to my code. Sorry, at CodeGolf people (and xem), if you all consider what I did unknowingly is copying another's work, I will happily delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [PYG 0.1](https://gist.github.com/Synthetica9/9796173) (17):

```
P(*Se(STP)-Se(Q))
```

prints

```
$
,
0
4
8
<
@
D
H
L
X
\
`
d
h
l
p
t
x
|


#
'
+
/
3
7
;
?
C
G
K
O
W
[
_
c
g
k
o
s
w
{
"
&
.
2
6
:
>
B
F
J
N
R
V
Z
^
b
f
j
n
r
v
z
~
    

!
%
1
5
9
=
A
E
I
M
U
Y
]
a
i
m
q
u
y
}
```

Not the shortest, but it gets the job done. Also, since I just created this "Language" (it's actually shortend Python), I'll explain what it does.

- `Q` gives the program's code
- `STP` gives all printable characters
- `Se` is equal to Python's `set`
- `-` substracts the two sets
- `*` is also the same as python's
- `P` prints it.

Knowing this, this would convert to the following python:
`for i in set(__import__("string").printable)-set(open(__file__).read()): print i`

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge, 44 characters

tested in http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground

```
$#~"01g`!#@_:01>g#1-#0*#:_!> #,!#g!_01g1+01p
```

it has exactly one quotation mark in the code, so that whenever it is executed, the program enters string mode, reading the code until it loops back to the same quotation mark, stops string mode and continues execution.

it does this for every printable ascii character, rejects it if it's in the code and continues.
maybe i'll golf it more later

Answer (score 1):

## J, 24 bytes

Another J solution in 24 characters:

```
'''{a.239-'-.~93{.32}.a.
```

- `a.` is the alphabet, this is, character 0 to 255 where some characters are replaced with box-drawing characters.
- `32}.a.` drops the first 32 characters of `a.` (the box-drawing and control characters)
- `93{.32}.a.` takes the first 93 characters of what remains. That is, ASCII characters 32 to 126. We don't take the tilde `~` or the closing curly brace `}` because they are part of the program.
- `'''{a.239-'-.~94{.32}.a.` removes the set of the characters `'{.a239-` (the remaining ASCII characters that are part of the program) from the character set generated in the previous step, yielding all ASCII characters that are not part of this program.

Answer (score 1):

## CBM BASIC v2.0 - 63

```
0fori=84+5to127.
3?chr$(i);:next
6rem "!#%&'*,-/<>@abdgjklmpqsuvw
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 41 bytes

```perl6
say [~] keys (' '..'~') (-)$*PROGRAM.comb # 41 bytes
```

```
IYZnCpl?W8|}K!^i"`Bhuvw6F<\S,=JrVLQE54%Xqg_1{/3+Tjx#Ht&;7>02@ND:9Udfz
```

The reason the order of the output is random is that the Set Minus operator `(-)` produces a Set, which is inherently unordered.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript/coffeescript/actionscript/more, 96

```
// #qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890~`!@$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>?
```

Other languages it works in are basically anything with // comments (and doesn't need something like `class a{public static void main(String[]a){`) This also works in Perl 5 (Thanks @BradGilbertb2gills for pointing that out!)

Comment: I was just about to comment that this would work in almost any language...

Comment: # qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890~`!@/$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>? Python - 95 bytes  **EDIT**: Damn code blocks

Comment: If you placed the `#` character before `qwerty` then it will also work in Perl 5.

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills cool!

Comment: Perl 5 will either see `//` as a null regex, or a defined-or operator. (`say undef // 1`) I'm not sure which. ( If it is the latter, it may only work on 5.10 or newer )

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 86 bytes

Naive implementation : for each character in the `0x20` - `0x7e` range, browse its codespace until it reaches the character or the end of the codespace.

```
' 'v1+>}:{:@@g:?!v{:}=?v30.
>  >00^   0+1v!?~<
^+1;?='~':<          ~~<
~:o       ^  >
```

Output :

```
"#$%&()*,-/2456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]_`abcdefhijklmnpqrstuwxyz|
```

This is definitely golfable, I'll try to improve the flow control later.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 94 bytes

```
f="l=...for i=32,126 do c=string.char(i)io.write(l:find(c,0,1)and\"\"or c)end"loadstring(f)(f)
```

Writes the algorithm in a string and uses loadstring to run it as a function passing in its string definition as the argument.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

## Smalltalk - 47

```
^#DI,($ to:$~)difference:thisContext sourceCode
```

This works in Squeak 6.x and produces the String:

```
'!"%&''*+-./0123456789;<=>?@ABEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]_`abgjklmpqvwyz{|}'
```

- `($ to:$~)` forms a left String ranging the 95 characters
- `thisContext sourceCode` produces a decompileString of the snippet
- `difference:` reject all the caracters from the left String that appears in the decompileString.
- `#DI`, which concatenates a Symbol with letters D and I to left String is here to make those 2 letters appear in code.
  It is necessary because the decompileString prefixes the snippet with `DoIt ^` which is the name of the pseudo-method. Those letters will thus be removed.
  Same for the leading `^` that indicates to return the result, it is in the decompileString so has to be in the code even if optional
  Letters o and t are already in source code, so it's OK.
- `'DI',` would work but result string is printed with quotes ' so source must not have quotes
- `"DI"` would be even shorter, unfortunately decompileString remove comments
- We could eliminate method name with `($ to:$~)difference:(thisContext sourceCode last:52)` but it is longer (52)

The code consumes 25 different characters, and thus produces 70 different characters (among 73, quote ' appearing 3 more times for printing the String)

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 24 bytes

```
{`{.` `~Rx={x\-`x=};x.}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/786oVovQSGhLqjCtroiRjehwrbWukKvtvr/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 126 bytes

The polyglot that lists all the printable ASCII characters and prints nothing is shorter, but this uses **only** valid brainfuck commands and prints the rest.

```
>+[-->---[-<]>]>+>++++++++++[<.+>-]+++++++++++++<+.+++>[<.+>-]>++++[<+++++++>-]<<+.++>[<.+>-]>++++[<++++++++>-]<+<+.++>[<.+>-]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v/fTjtaV9dOV1c3Wtcm1i7WTttOGw6ibfS07XRjtZGBjbYekLSDStlBlEHlgAI2YHns0mB5bRQF//8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 80

Compliant with current rules, I think, no loopholes anyway

```
<?=join(array_diff(range(' ','~'),str_split(' \'(),;<=?\_acdefghijlnoprsty~')));
```

Just gets the difference between the full set and the chars I used.

Self Tests like this, if first and second line of output match, the first line is a valid solution

```
<?=join(array_diff(range(' ','~'),str_split(' \'(),;<=?\_acdefghijlnoprsty~')));

$used = count_chars(file(__FILE__)[0],3);
$ascii = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~';
$unused = str_replace(str_split($used), '', $ascii);

echo "\n".$unused;
echo "\n".$used;
echo "\n";
```

Comment: does neither use nor print the space character (`0x20`), but can be fixed without adding bytes.

Comment: Good catch.  Replacing `!` with ` ` seems to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

## [A Pear Tree](https://esolangs.org/wiki/A_Pear_Tree), 86 bytes

```
`~1!2@3#4$5%6^7&8*9(0)-_=+[]{}\|;':",./<>?bcfhjklmnoqsuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

It appears the only error message is "a partridge".

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9QtSE0s0i0pSk39/z@hzlDRyMFY2UTFVNUszlzNQstSw0BTN95WOzq2ujamxlrdSklHT9/Gzj4pOS0jKzsnNy@/sLi0rLyissrRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIy6v9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Flipbit](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Flipbit), 369 bytes

```
^>>>>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^<^>>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^>>.^.<^>.>^<[^<]^>>>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^<^>>>.^.^<^>.^.<^<^>>.<^>.<<<<^>^>^>^>^>.^.<^>.^.^<^<^>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^<^>>>.^.^<^>.^.^<^<^>>.^.^<^>.^.<<<<^>>>>.<^>.^.<<^>^>^.^.<^>.^.<<<^>>>.^.<^>.^.<<^>^>.<^>.^.<^>.<<^<<^<^>>>>>.^.<^>.^.<<^>>.^.<^>.^.^<<^<^>>>.^.<^>.^.<<^>>.^.<^>.^.<^>[^<].<<<<^>>>^.<^>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8vJLEjKLPn/P84OBPTi9OJs4qAUkIEuABLCqgjEt4uziY6ziY0jwyCoGhDHBgji7GAQajTJ7oGZCzbMDmo0iA82Fm4qVBqJD7bUBm4xUMAGag2aMmSnIRyCTR5IgsIF7hiI@P//AA)

Assumes that the output can contain characters outside the ASCII range, so here is a hexdump:

```
00000000: 2021 2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b 2c2d 2f30   !"#$%&'()*+,-/0
00000010: 3132 3334 3536 3738 393a 3b3d 3f41 4042  123456789:;=?A@B
00000020: 4344 4546 4748 494a 4b4c 4d4e 4f5f 5d5c  CDEFGHIJKLMNO_]\
00000030: 5b5a 5859 5150 5253 5557 5654 6061 6362  [ZXYQPRSUWVT`acb
00000040: 6667 6564 6968 6a6b 6f6e 6c6d 7071 7273  fgedihjkonlmpqrs
00000050: 7475 7677 7879 7a7b 7d7f c0c1 c3c2 c5c4  tuvwxyz{}.......
00000060: c7c6 c9c8 cbca cdcc cfce dedc ddda dbd9  ................
00000070: d8d0 d1d3 d2d4 d6d7 d5e1 e0e2 e3e7 e6e4  ................
00000080: e5e8 e9eb eaee efed ec7e 7c              .........~|
```

Don't you dare ask me how it works. As this (ab)used a bug which has no been fixed, test with [this](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Flipbit/tree/b0ab39e86b1898f16bd817dc36f4e697187eeac0) commit.

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 66 bytes

```perl
$s=q{$_=chr,"\$s=q{$s};eval\$s"!~/\Q$_/&&print for 32..126};eval$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@l2LawWiXeNjmjSEcpBsIrrrVOLUvMAfKUFOv0YwJV4vXV1AqKMvNKFNLyixSMjfT0DI3MIIpUiv//BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 bytes

```
#[o_d#$ k"[o_d$k1!"1
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=I1tvX2QjJCBrIltvX2QkazEhIjE=&input=)

#### How it works

```
#[o_d#$ k"[o_d$k1!"1

#[o                   Map range(91) with...
   _d#$                 Apply chr(n+36)...
        k"[o_d$k1!"     and remove these chars from it...
                   1    in case sensitive mode.
                      Implicit output (result is Array; comma-joined)
```

Dealing with the quotes turned out to be nasty, so I reduced the range to start at `$` (36) instead of  (32).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>46</s>, 37

```
puts (?!..?~).to_a-IO.read($0).chars
```

Creates a range of characters from ! to ~, reads the current file and subtracts the characters in the current file from the range, then prints them all out.

Inspiration from prior Ruby post of Doorknob.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 70 bytes

```php
for($c=31;++$c<127;)count_chars(file(__FILE__)[0])[$c]||print chr($c);
```

### PHP, 80 bytes

```php
<?=join(array_diff(range(" ","~"),str_split(count_chars(file(__FILE__)[0],3))));
```

[Try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb8c80fb149769eeaead32a3d7d24754023f04d2).

Require PHP 5.4 or later (released 2012-03-01) for indexing the function result.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 79 bytes:

```sql
PRint upper('abcdefghijlkmnoqstuvwxyz')--!"#$%&*+,./0123456789:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

Kinda cheaty, everything after `--` is a comment.

Less cheaty, much longer (**143 bytes**):

```sql
WITH UX AS(SELECT 33D union ALL SELECT D+1FROM UX WHERE D<126)
select CHAR(D)from UX where charindex(char(D),'acdefhilmnorstuwx()+<,''=01236')=0
```

Must be run on a case-insensitive database. This uses a recursive number table to generate values from 33 to 126, and displays the `CHAR()` of each, excluding any that are in a string (that simply re-lists all characters used elsewhere in the code).

SQL keywords are not case-sensitive, so I vary the case to cover both upper and lower of each letter used. `CHARINDEX` on a case-insensitive database then excludes both the upper and lower of each in the string, saving me some characters.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 65

```
print(''.join(set(map(chr,range(32,127)))-set(open('q').read())))
```

Name the file 'q'. Run with `python3 q`. If 'q' is an unacceptable filename the file can be named '.py' for an additional 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
$><<([*?%...?~]-"#%><chars.[*?!-]()".chars)*""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkYjWsteVU9Pz74uVldJWdXOJjkjsahYDyiqqBuroamkB@Zraikp/f8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 60 bytes

> Inspired by Iszi's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15374/80745). See also AdmBorkBork's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60906/80745) with another approach.

```powershell
$t=gc(gv My* -v|% I*e)|% t*y
[char[]](32..126)|?{$_-notin$t}
```

where:

- `gv My* -v` is alias and [shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) for `Get-Variable MyInvocation -Value`.
- `|% I*e` is shortcut for `|% InvocationName`.
- `|% t*y` is shortcut for `|% ToCharArray`.
- and first line means: store to the variable `$t` a char array  that is read from a file with a name that is taken from the properties of the current script.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 bytes

Bah! Stoopid `k` and its stoopid case-insensitivity costing me 2 bytes!

```
;EkQ+"+QkE;"E
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0VrUSsiK1FrRTsiRQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```perl6
say [~] keys (" ".."~") (-)"say o(\\\".~)-cmbkey[]".comb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVIhui5WITu1slhBQ0lBSU9PqU5JU0FDV1MJJJevERMTo6RXp6mbnJsEVBQdq6SXnJ@b9P8/AA)

Comment: you didn't update the TIO link

Comment: Updated the link, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), 14 bytes

```
pE'a-"pE'a-\""
```

Just performs a diff between all printable ASCII character and the few unique chars in this program.

### Explanation

```
pE'a-"pE'a-\""
p              - Print...
  'a-          -   Printable ASCII range
 E             -   That isn't found in...
     "pE'a-\"" -   The characters used in this program
```

Comment: Hm, does this remove ``\`` from the printable ASCII character set?

Answer (score 1):

### VTL-2, 194 bytes

```
33 ~=#-1
51 ~=~+1
53 #=51*((~=35)+(~=(35+1))+(~=(35+5))+(~=(35+5+1))+(~=(35+5+1+1))
55 #=51*((~=(35+5+3))+(~=(35+5+5))+(~=(51-1-1))+(~=51)+(~=53)
111 #=51*(55+5+1=~
113 $=~
115 #=51*(1-(~=(115+5+5
```

Prints `` !"%&',./0246789:;<>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|} ``. It's about double the length of the comment approach, but much more interesting. I had to use *some* digits, and restricting it to 1, 3, and 5 seemed to work the best... though I haven't proven this. Line-by-line explanation:

33: Assigns the variable `~` to the current line number (`#`) less 1. Originally I was going to use `!` and be able to start printing from 34 on, but... `!` is a system variable.

51: Increments the value in `~`

53, 55, 111: These all basically say `IF ~ == 35 OR ~ == 36 OR ~ == 40 [...] GOTO 51`. VTL relies heavily on system variables. `#` is the line number variable - as in line 33, we can pull the value of the current line number, but if we *assign* a value to `#`, it's a GOTO. The initial `#=` is this assignment, everything else is evaluation. Any given `~=35` type evaluation returns one for true (equality) or zero otherwise. We do as many of these as fit in a line (72 characters), sum them, and multiply this by our target line number. If any of those evaluations were true, we end up with `#=51`; if not, we end up with `#=0`, essentially a NOP.

113: Output character corresponding to code point.

115: Same sort of GOTO construction as above, except we're looping back `IF ~ != 125`. So, first we have to see if `~` does equal 125, then subtract that from 1 to make it a NOT.

Keeping in mind the line length restrictions, the lazy commented version comes in at 93 bytes:

```
12340 )"#$%&'(*+,-./:;<=>?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU!
56789 )VWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~@
```

...although I can't actually enter this because the `@` chokes it. And now I know why: "At any time before hitting Return, the entire line may be erased by typing the At-signcharacter ‘@’ (Shift-P or “Cancel” on some terminals.)". So the non-printing commented version is purely theoretical, and some code would have to be written to at least print the `@`... which would mean code to print the characters used in that code, etc...

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <sup><s>40</s></sup> 38 bytes

```
for c ({!..~})fgrep $c $0>%||printf $c
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY31dLyixSSFTSqFfX06mo109KLUgsUVJIVVAzsVGtqCooy80rSgHyIaqgmmGYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 48 bytes

```julia
print.(setdiff(' ':'~',"print.(sedf' :~,\\\")"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69ET6M4tSQlMy1NQ11B3Uq9Tl1HCS6ekqauYFWnExMTo6SppKn5Pzk/JVXBVqEosVxJSYlU3UAtXPmlJQWlJXAjFJVVVNW0tHX1DQyNjE1MzcwtLK1tbO3sHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXz9/AMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomPj4hMSk5LTM7Kyc3LzC0vLyisqq6prakHGczkkFhenFpUooDtKAezyRx2rFCAu0FSosVPILE7NLSiphGuCqlkJVYOk5D8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rec](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Rec), 95 bytes

```python
[0^ !"#$%&'()*+,-./123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVZrW9MwFP7eX3Ecalt3YROvw@EVFK@IeB0DuzbbIiWJSTo6cfz1mbTb2CVdecwX6HLOe@5vDhvIHiUbI3zKKJcgBsIS0vNPoAHNlmUFqAM8Iscc@Q7jtFuCALWjrrrd8UKB3LoF6hT2kYw4gb4XRkjdnfWQ7CEOZwgIQgFICm2OvBOgkQTaAU9J4BBBSCkrJAhMcqVXTf6XfJDC6pMK6utHECKSOOFeXuuDO6B/bSqhFmACdrV2e@PO3Xv3Hzy05yUn0pJvVcEjwVSvXLuCpj5JbioeY4gETvrBKHPcW7VqERPpTB1x3SV9pBJ2BdRVMCicC7bRAHvd4GmC19RBFRtQy0M4PFwJUb4CRN2AEKuCzmTIyk9l8yJu5ca7aTJVgv68tVK@aW1NKfXzDB6Zm4hQOWvDXFiezsUBj5CVZ6dlsMM9LBDskgDF25xT7tgRaXuhR3w1VW2urCMp7NycNQ3QIeqjEBZrmxjF3Z5UN3roiob78exqfXPUKbRqvcSLBG7ixwr58rJ8yyyfOpi09nJpQ6xyc6yRoDFNQ7FWT5RUP2eEo0tkjkb38YQCZ9Bdo7BKfaxdz4bTJyHDZd9TEkwcXbrzKZGYLLbRGuxQnlJyF5MusIgzKpDIa4g9Q0MwrplnpqVz22o/izdmqQwTFkkFlovGMn1SUCovfo/PeZcLyLNIaSAqQgaYVFQZAqfmWllVtK/yCpRr/031lAdOnB@IMI2vJ/SMnnqxUy1B8oS5WZOqRaevnf5qVbAQzPNRFm8lKmUTOaQV6djOuZYZunB@iTq0x7SbG1HbENFksVgmS6WeXuogNO9OwVbFoUudNp/2VklPndWaQ7AVuQk57ilXfdigmNRaHMhLmkGxj5iE7eQPpgQ8ATNVVl5qOOSmNZNcDyTW1D1Ze7hHumghcr0uGUndWpgB11osgaiDIa7lGqAYS93l1syLlGxvljWmSV4oFEbN6hFcK6xdv3HTVvtMsVSurE@3ofrmo8bW4ydPnz1/sb3z8tXu6zdv373/sPdx/9PB5y9fv33/cXj802v7alvs9vCvk/CUUPabCxn1z@LBn/O/w4vWSNmwZldJd/QP)

Answer (score 1):

## [ForWhile](https://esolangs.org/wiki/ForWhile), 26 bytes

`!$%&'*,-./012348 69(57+#)"`

uses the first 26 printable Ascii characters, prints the remaining 69 characters
`` ~}|{zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@?>=<;: ``

[online interpreter](https://bsoelch.github.io/OneChar.js/?lang=forwhile&src=ISQlJicqLC0uLzAxMjM0OCA2OSg1NysjKSI=)

## Explanation

```
!$%&'*,-./012348 \ operations without observable side effects
69(57+#)         \ print ascii characters ':' to '~'
"                \ start a string literal
                 \ for-while ignores unclosed strings at end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript: (96 bytes long, prints nothing, throws an error)

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

or

### Valid JavaScript (97 bytes long, prints nothing)

```
' !"#$%&()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'
```

Answer (score 0):

**F# - 66**

```
Set.iter(printf"%c")(set[' '..'~']-set"Set.ir(pnf\"%c)s[' ~]-\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript 94**

```
a="",r="for(v=32;v<128;)c=String.fromCharCode(v++),a+=r.indexOf(c)<0?c:\"\"; alert(a)";eval(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

**PHP (110 characters)**

```
<?php
$w=file_get_contents(__FILE__);
$i=32;
while ($i++<126)
echo(strpos($w,chr($i))===false)?chr($i):'';
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 43 characters

```
$><<([*' '..?~]-open($0).read.split(''))*''
```

Output:

```
!"#%&+,/123456789:;=@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\^_`bcfghjkmquvwxyz{|}
```

Answer (score 0):

### k4 (31)

```
-1 x@&~(x:"c"$32+!95)in*0:.z.f;
```

save in a file, name doesn't matter (except that the extension has to be `.k`), and run with q.

```
$ q aq.k 2>/dev/null
#%',/4678<=>?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abdeghjklmopqrstuvwy{|}
```

works by getting the name of current script file, reading it, removing its contents from the list of all printable ascii, and printing what's left.

if we dispense with the trailing newline in the printout, we can save one character (the `-` at the beginning of the code)

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy: 52 chars

```
print(((' '..'~')-new File('a').text.grep()).join())
```

// print all characters from `'#'` to `'~'`, except those present in the file itself (the name of the source file is 'a').

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon because it's assuming that file `a` has all the missing characters in it. This solution exploits a common loophole, and is therefore invalid.

Comment: @Magic Octopus Urn - No. The file 'a' is the name of the program itself. The program simply reads itself, and then removes all the characters it contains from the specified range of characters.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 99 Characters

```
echo implode('',array_diff(array_map('chr',range(33,126)),str_split(file_get_contents(__FILE__))));
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 129 Bytes

This one is a bit more unique than some of what I've seen. It reads the program's source into a variable then iterates of the ASCII table.

To run you must save your code in a  file called "f".

```
use IO;func main(){f=File.readText("f");for(c=0;c<128;c++){c=Convert.toChar(c);g=1;foreach(d in f)if(c==d)g=0;if(g==1)print(c);}}
```

Run and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=6d301b1e28c16c3aa6707c1a6392cb25)

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript II, 82 bytes

Well, that's just ridiculous.

```
( %&'*+,-./12345789:<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNORSTUVWXYZ\^_`bcdghijkmovwxyz{|}~)P6;q!p#Q$
```

One ridiculously long unexecuted conditional, followed by the commands `P6;q!p#Q$`.

Output:

```
null
"false"true"0"
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy, <s>90</s> 78 bytes

```
(32..126).each{print'(32.16)each{print\'\\dxOf+?:}'.indexOf(it)+1?'':(char)it}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Mouse-2002](https://github.com/catb0t/newmouse/blob/master/mouse.c), <s>105</s> 95

```
$!"#%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

<s>Contains a bunch of unprintables; hexdump (reversible with `xxd -r`):</s>

Does nothing, and is not a comment; it just so happens everything after `$` is ignored.

---

A *real* answer would start like

```
zh+i:(i.127<^i.!'i.b+i:)
```

But you'd need a lot of if-statements and it would just get ridiculously long.

Comment: "is not a comment, ... everything after`$` is ignored." Pretty sure that's the definition of a comment

Comment: @MDXF no, it is the end of the program

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 34 bytes, noncompeting

```
"!$%&'()*+[,.]/:<=>?@^_`{|}";~J\J-
```

I'm going the no-op, print chars route

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%22%21%24%25%26%27%28%29%2a%2B%5B%2C.%5D%2F%3A%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D%22%3B%7EJ%5CJ-)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 71 bytes

Taking as the range of "printable" characters ASCII 32-126, this takes the complement of the full set of characters (`CharacterRange[32, 126]`) and the used set of characters (`"Charactes@Rngplm[32,16]"`).

```
Complement[CharacterRange[32, 126],Characters@"Charactes@Rngplm[32,16]"]
```

{"!", "#", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "~", 
"`", "{", "}", "|", "\", "<", ">", ".", ";", "\"", "?", "'", "/", 
":", " ", "0", "4", "5", "7", "8", "9", "A", "b", "B", "d", "D", "E", 
"f", "F", "G", "H", "i", "I", "j", "J", "k", "K", "L", "M", "N", "o", 
"O", "P", "q", "Q", "S", "T", "u", "U", "v", "V", "w", "W", "x", "X", 
"y", "Y", "z", "Z", "$"}

Answer (score 0):

## Perl6, 66

```
(63..96)>>.chr.join.print #!"$%&/+-*:;<=0124578abdefghklmqsuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 0):

## ISOLADOS, 7369 bytes (non-competing)

```
ISOLAADOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAADOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS ISOLAADOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOS ISOLAAAAAAADOS ISOLAAADOS
```

Comment: link to interpreter or something?

Comment: Link to interpreter or something?

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 61 bytes

```
[32,126|B=chr$(a)~instr(A,B)|\?B}##$(),1236=?ABB[\achinrst|}~
```

[Are we allowing new languages on old challenges yet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12877/lets-allow-newer-languages-versions-for-older-challenges)

### Explanation

```
[32,126|      FOR a = 32 TO 126
B=chr$(a)       Set B$ to the char code a
~instr(A,B)   IF A$ contains B$
|             THEN do nothing
\?B}          ELSE print B$
#             Define a literal A$ that has every char in this program once.
 #$(),1236=?ABB[\achinrst|}~
```

Usually, QBIC would delimit a literal with a backtck ('`'), so that's the one char we can't have in a literal. However, the backtick is auto-added on open literals at EOF.

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 81 bytes

```php
<?php $w=file(__FILE__)[0];foreach(range(' ','')as$i){echo!strpos($w,$i)?$i:'';}
```

Shortest by-the-book PHP submission so far, built upon @michal.hubczyk 's answer with a few golf twists. Interestingly enough, adding the `<?php` prolog saves some bytes off the whole solution, thanks to the use of `file()[0]` modern php array-dereferencing on the one-liner file instead of the classic `file_get_contents()`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go0BBpdw2LTMnVSM@3s3TxzU@XjPaINY6Lb8oNTE5Q6MoMS89VUNdQV1HvV5dM7FYJVOzOjU5I1@xuKSoIL9YQ6VcByhkr5Jppa5uXfv/PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 155 bytes

Includes +1 for `-A`

```
((((((()()()()){}){}){})<>[()()()])[()])((((()()()){})){}{})<>((()()()()){}){({}[()]<(({})())>)}{}({}()())<>{{({}<>[()]<(({})())><>)}{}<>(({}())()())<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMCNCFQs7oWimzsoiFCsZrRIAKhCiQLxGA1aDo1qmtBim00gAyQmJ0mUBmQDVZgY1cNUgA2GEmJDVgRyCiQOk2oUqDA////dR0B)

```
# Push 32 on this stack and 18, 28 and 29 to the other
# 18, 28 and 29 are the distances between the sets of braces 
((((((()()()()){}){}){})<>[()()()])[()])((((()()()){})){}{})<>

# For 0 to 8
((()()()()){}){({}[()]<

    # Push TOS, TOS + 1
    (({})())

# end For 0 to 8
>)}{}

# Push TOS + 2 
# skips '(' and ')'
({}()())

# For each value on the off stack (18, 28, 28)
<>{

    # For 0 to that number
    {({}<>[()]<

        # Push TOS, TOS + 1
        (({})())

    # End for 0 to that number
    ><>)}{}

    # Push TOS + 1, TOS + 3 (skips this set of braces)
    <>(({}())()())<>

# End for each value on the off stack (18, 28, 28)
}<>
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>45 44</s> 41 bytes

```matlab
setdiff([33:126 ''],'setdif([3:126''],)')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/OLUkJTMtTSPa2NjK0MhMQV09VkcdIggUAwmBRDTVNf//BwA)

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, <s>78</s> 63 bytes

```
FOR I=32TO 126?CHR$(I)*(INSTR(LOAD("TXT:_",0),CHR$(I))<0);
NEXT
```

Assumes the program is saved in a file named `_` (which sounds like cheating to me but apparently this is ok)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 96

```js
eval(l="for(e=32,x='';e<127;e++)v=eval('\"\\\\x'+e.toString(16)+'\"'),x+=-1==l.indexOf(v)?v:''")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 94 bytes, does nothing

If anyone wants the full codeset between `0x20` and `0x7e` here you go...

```python
#!"$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

This is just a comment, and I posted for boredom purposes.
First *Python* answer doing nothing.

Comment: It's not the first.   https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12370/69229

Comment: That's too general

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua 5.3](https://www.lua.org/), 89 bytes

```lua
print(_VERSION)--!"#$%&'*+,/01246789:;<=>?@ABCDFGHJKMPQTUWXYZ[\]^`bcdefghjklmoqsvwxyz{|}~
```

Prints `Lua 5.3`. Same principle can be applied to other versions, though you may need to add a byte or two depending on the version.

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 198 B

The Pascal programming language does not prescribe any particular character encoding (e. g. ASCII).
Pascal only requires that the *implementation-defined* character set *includes* characters *necessary* to write Pascal source code.
Thus e. g. the existence of `~` is not guaranteed as such character is not necessary to successfully write Pascal source code.

Therefore this submission does not restrict the output to the `chr(32)` – `chr(126)` range, because there is no assertion that `chr(32) = ' '` or `chr(126) ≤ maxChar`.
The *implementation-defined* constant `maxChar` is available in any processor compliant with ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” and denotes the largest available value of the built‑in `char` data type.

```pascal
PROGRAM P(OUTPUT);VAR C:CHAR;BEGIN FOR C IN[CHR(0)..MAXCHAR]-[' ','-',';',':','.','''','(',')','[',']','0','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','M','N','O','P','R','T','U','V','W','X']DO WRITE(C)END.
```

The `for … in` set member iteration statement and range-based set constructor (e. g. `[1..3]` = `[1, 2, 3]`) are defined by ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”.
The particular order the `char` values are printed is *implementation-dependent*.
You may alter the casing of letters in any way you like (subject to availability, i. e. it is not guaranteed that lower *and* uppercase letters *coexist*).

**147 B**:
Some submissions use the source code file as input.
In Pascal the availability of the source code file during execution time is not guaranteed.
You can of course feed back the source code file as input to the `program`, but technically this outputs the characters not present in `input`:

```pascal
program p(input,output);var c:char;m:set of char;begin m:=[];while not EOF do begin read(c);m:=m+[c]end;for c in[chr(0)..maxChar]-m do write(c)end.
```