# QWERTY Quine Creation

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, quine, sorting

#### Challenge

Create a quine, that instead of outputting it's source, output's it's source QWERTY-sorted.

#### What is QWERTY sorting?

QWERTY sorting is sorting code by the QWERTY keyboard. Anything higher or more left is greater (`q` > `Q`, `\` > `/`) with presedence on higher. To check, find the locations of the two characters to compare. Find which character occurs first in the following table (left to right, up to down). The first character is the smaller one.

```
qwertyuiop[]\
asdfghjkl;'
zxcvbnm,./
QWERTYUIOP{}|
ASDFGHJKL:"
ZXCVBNM<>?
1234567890-=!@#$%^&*()_+~`
```

(there is a trailing space and linefeed)

Examples:

```
Code Golf -> eoodflGC 
Programming -> rroiagnmmP
```

(note trailing space on `Code Golf`)

#### Specifications

- Only characters in the above list are allowed in the source code!
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).
- Only [Proper Quines](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine/4878#4878) are allowed (adapted to QWERTY sort).
- Output must be in *increasing* QWERTY order.

Comment: You should make explicit that [proper quines](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4878) are required.

Comment: :D Jelly can't win this, it is mostly non-ascii!!!

Comment: Javascript is clearly winning this. In what else language can you print out a function source code in default?

Comment: I've voted to close this question, as I can't understand what is the challenge at all.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος What part don't you understand? It reads pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Bálint you don't need that feature to win.

Comment: Why is `f` > `G` > `l`? The keyboard diagram implies that all lowercase comes before all uppercase, but these examples imply that the upper and lower cases of a letter are right next to each other, i.e. `qQwWeE...` is sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print every character your program doesn't have](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/print-every-character-your-program-doesnt-have)

Comment: "Anything higher or more left is greater" - This is somewhat ambiguous, what about `w` and `a`? `w` is above `a` but also to the right of it? I think you need to say which takes precedence.

Comment: @MorganThrapp It's not clear enough for everyone to understand.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Okay, but can you point out some specific parts that you find unclear so that NoOne can fix them? There's nothing wrong with finding something unclear, we're all just trying to make the challenges the best we can.

Comment: I've VTC this as unclear for the reasons that algorithmshark and FryAmTheEggman pointed out -- the natural expectation of the sentence structure, plus the qwerty diagram, plus the seemingly incongruent examples, don't lead to a solid spec.

Comment: @TimmyD Thanks, yeah, looking at those I see now what the issue is. I was honestly just confused.

Comment: With that said, I might also be not understanding what this adds beyond a normal quine. To use the Ruby example from Martin's linked "Proper Quine" post, something like `_="_=%p;puts _%%_";puts _%_` with the string literal sorted by hand would seem to fit the requirements, so that would mean that plenty of quines can be transferred here with minimal adjustment.

Comment: I can't vote to close this again, 'cause "I've alerady voted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CJam, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
{`"_~"+{"#$_+~`"`#}$}_~
```

*Thanks to @MartinBüttner for golfing off 2 bytes!*

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=e2AiX34iK3siIyRfK35gImAjfSR9X34&input=)

#### How it works

````
{                   }_~  Define, copy and execute a code block.

   `                       Create a string representation of the code block.
  "_~"+                    Append that string.
       {          }$       Sort the characters by the following:
        "#$_+~`"`#           Compute the 0-based index of the character in that
                             string. Returns -1 if not found.
                           Since `$' is stable, all characters with tied index -1
                           will appear at the beginning, in their original order.
                           This places {{}} at the beginning, followed by
                           """"##$$___++~~~```.
````