# Trying to optimize a solution to a puzzle with PHP

Tags: code-golf, tips, php

I got inspired by this: [Print every character your program doesn't have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12368/print-every-character-your-program-doesnt-have)

But with the exception that the letters have to be between ASCII 32 to 126. We started fooling around with it at the office with PHP and this is the best we could come up with:

`<? while($i++<95)if(!strstr(file(__FILE__)[0],$a=chr($i+31)))echo$a;`

Is it possible to make it even shorter with PHP?

Comment: For those who have voted to close this as off-topic: [tag:tips] questions with an objective winning criterion (such as [tag:code-golf]) are *not* off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear, because at PPCG we have specific rules and banned loopholes for quine-style challenges, including reading your own source code as your snippet does, but we don't know what would be kosher for you and your office buddies.

Comment: Also, I think this question would benefit from more explanation and context, as is usual on Stack Exchange. What is the code doing, and what golfing ideas have you used? What alternatives have you or others tried? What parts do you suspect could be shorter? In general, I think questions that just say "I have a task and a piece of code, how can it be shorter?" are closer to single-languages golf challenges than tips questions?