# Spanning tree of a rectangular grid

Tags: code-golf, grid, graph-theory

### Background

A spanning tree ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree)) of an undirected graph is a subgraph that is a tree which includes all of the vertices of the original graph. The following is an example of a spanning tree of a 4-by-4 grid graph.

[image]

### Task

Given two positive integers `w` and `h`, output **any valid spanning tree of the grid graph** which has `w` vertices horizontally and `h` vertices vertically. There are lots of valid answers; just output one of them. Your code is even allowed to give different outputs across runs, as long as all of them are valid.

### Input and output

The input is two positive integers `w` and `h`.

The output is a representation of a spanning tree. **The output format is restricted to "a list of pairs of numbered vertices"**, in order to prevent various boring answers (as discussed in the sandbox). Also, the vertex numbering should be in **row-major order**, e.g.

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3
|   |   |   |
4 - 5 - 6 - 7
|   |   |   |
8 - 9 - 10- 11
```

or

```
(0,0) - (0,1) - (0,2) - (0,3)
  |       |       |       |
(1,0) - (1,1) - (1,2) - (1,3)
  |       |       |       |
(2,0) - (2,1) - (2,2) - (2,3)
```

You can choose to use 0-based or 1-based indexing for vertices. Also, you may output nested or flattened arrays.

### Scoring & winning criterion

The standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest valid submission in bytes wins.

### Example I/O

#### `w=3, h=2`

If you want to output the following graph

```
+-+-+
| |
+ +-+
```

The list-of-vertex-pairs representation will be (using 0-based indexing for example):

```
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4), (4, 5)]
```

or

```
[((0, 0), (0, 1)),
 ((0, 0), (1, 0)),
 ((0, 1), (0, 2)),
 ((0, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (1, 2))]
```

#### `w=1, h=1`

The graph is a single vertex with no edges, and its only spanning tree is the graph itself. Your code should output an empty list (which means no edges).

Comment: Does rule anything prevent us from always zig-zagging through the array? E.g. 0 → 1 → 2 → 3 ↓ 7 ← 6 ← 5 ← 4 ↓ 8 → 9 → 10 → 11

Comment: @Adam It doesn't, as far as I see. You can also simply use, for example, a vertical line combined with many horizontal ones.

Comment: Can we input h and w in unary? Can we input them as a grid made of a specific character?

Comment: @someone Unary: yes, but only if it's the most natural representation of a positive integer in your language of choice. Grid input: no.

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 9 bytes

```
|\'2':+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6qJUTdSt9JWtOLiSlMwVjABACnuA9o=)

this is a composition equivalent to the lambda `{|\'2'+!x}`. the trailing `:` forces `!` (and therefore the whole composition) to be monadic.

```
 !2 3         /odometer
(0 0 0 1 1 1
 0 1 2 0 1 2)
 +!2 3        /flip
(0 0
 0 1
 0 2
 1 0
 1 1
 1 2)
 2':+!2 3     /pairs (sliding window size 2)
((0 0;0 1)
 (0 1;0 2)
 (0 2;1 0)
 (1 0;1 1)
 (1 1;1 2))
 |\'2':+!2 3  /cumulative(\) max(|) each(')
((0 0;0 1)
 (0 1;0 2)
 (0 2;1 2)
 (1 0;1 1)
 (1 1;1 2))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
lambda w,h:zip(R(w-1)+R(w*h),R(1,w*h))
R=range
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaFcJ8OqKrNAI0ijXNdQUxtIaWVo6gRpGOqAGJpcQbZFiXnpqf8LijLzShTSNEx0jDW5uJSUlLgMdHUNdXWNdHWNuWoUFKCIy0RBwVRBwUxBwRxZ1EJBwVJBwdBAwdAQpPc/AA)

**49 bytes**

```python
lambda w,h:[(i-w**(i>=w),i)for i in range(1,w*h)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctLCsIwFEbheVbxk1EScqFp66OFuhF1ENGYC5qWUAiCe48IDoQz@uAsrzXOqa1hOtWHf16uHsXG8aiYijGKD1PRlnWYMxickH2635SzxUR9rkvmtCKo3nZaCCmlaIgcUUvUiTfwS/TABtgCu3/dAwPgGjj3fesH)

Both of these produce a list corresponding to a spanning tree like this (for `w=4, h=3`):

```python
0--1--2--3
|  |  |  |
4  5  6  7
|  |  |  |
8  9  10 11
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts for `[h,w]` from stdin. Prints pairs of `[y,x]` coordinates.

```apl
2⍮/,↑⊢∘⌽\↓⍳⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@Gz3qXaev86ht4qOuRY86Zjzq2RvzqG3yo97NQHX/gSq4gHSwK5AID1Z3LUvNK1FXUA9OLS7OzM8LKMoEc72K8/PUuUAk0NhqoFIgBSS9gv39HvXuqv2vAAYFXMYKJlwwtpGCMQA)

`⎕` prompt for numeric input from the console

`⍳` an array of those dimensions containing the **ɩ**ndices of an array of those dimensions

`↓` split into list of rows

`⊢∘⌽\` [boustrophedonise](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150153/43319)

`↑` combine rows into matrix

`,` ravel matrix into list

`2⍮/` adjacent pairs (lit. for every overlapping run of 2 elements, juxtapose the 2 elements)

Comment: `⌈\¨2,/⊂¨,⍳⎕` is 11. i believe you can shorten it even more with your extensions.

Comment: @ngn Another clever ngn-scan! But it has no connection to my solution, and even makes a different tree. Go ahead and post `⌈\¨2⍮/,⍤⍳` in Extended.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195408/spanning-tree-of-a-rectangular-grid/195488#195488

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
*L©¹<Lì®¦ø
```

-2 bytes by porting [*@xnor*'s Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195413/52210), but is 1-based instead. So it will output the graph in this format (i.e. `w=5, h=3`):

```
1--2--3--4--5
|  |  |  |  |
6  7  8  9  10
|  |  |  |  |
11 12 13 14 15
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9vc2FiaWX//ypMwqnCuTxMw6zCrsKmw7j//zUKMw)

**Explanation:**

```python
*           # Multiply the (implicit) width and height inputs with each other
 L          # Create a list in the range [1,w*h]
  ©         # Store this list in variable `®` (without popping)
   ¹<       # Push the width-input again, and decrease it by 1
     L      # Create a list in the range [1,w-1]
      ì     # Prepend it in front of the earlier list
       ®    # Push the list [1,w*h] from variable `®` again,
        ¦   # and remove the 1 to make it the range [2,w*h]
         ø  # Zip/transpose to create pairs of the two lists
            # (after which this list of pairs is output implicitly as result)
```

---

**Original 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
*LIä2Å€R}˜ü‚
```

1-based. Will output the graph in this format (i.e. `w=5, h=3`):

```
1--2--3--4--5
|
6--7--8--9--10
            |
11-12-13-14-15
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//ypMScOkMsOF4oKsUn3LnMO84oCa//81CjM)

**Explanation:**

```python
*             # Multiply the (implicit) width and height inputs with each other
 L            # Create a list in the range [1,w*h]
  Iä          # Split it into the height-input amount of equal-length parts
    2Å€ }     # Apply to every 2nd (index % 2 == 0) item:
       R      #  Reverse the inner list
         ˜    # Then flatten it to a single list of integers again
          ü   # Apply to each overlapping pair of values:
           ‚  #  Pair them together
              # (after which this list of pairs is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes

```r
function(w,h)cbind(a<-1:(h*w-1),a+w^!a%%w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCr8D@tNC@5JDM/T6NcJ0MzOSkzL0Uj0UbX0EojQ6tc11BTJ1G7PE4xUVW1XPN/moaxjonmfwA)

Creates the spanning graph

```r
1-2-3
    |
4-5-6
    |
7-8-9
```

Node `i` is connected to node `i+1` in general, or to node `i+w` if `i` is a multiple of `w`. This corresponds to a connecting node `i` to node `i+w^d` where `d=1` if `i` is a multiple of `w`, and `d=0` otherwise.

Comment: Nice that this method's solution for a 3x3 traces out a 3.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
⌈\¨2⍮/,⍤⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OA5KOejphDK4we9a7T13nUu@RR7@b//9MUjBVMuNIUjBSMAQ)

[Adám's golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/195408/spanning-tree-of-a-rectangular-grid/195420?noredirect=1#comment465224_195420) of [my algorithm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195425/24908)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>44</s> 41 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 44 is still 44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194711/18535)</sup>

```ruby
->w,h{(1...w*h).map{|x|[x,x+=x%w<1?w:1]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165cJ6Naw1BPT69cK0NTLzexoLqmoia6QqdC27ZCtdzG0L7cyjC2tvZ/gUJatImOcSwXl5KSEpehrq6Rrq6xrq4JlwIM1HCZ6uqa6eqa6@paIIta6hoa6Boa6hoagbT@BwA)

1-based solution

Answer (score 1):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com), 215 bytes

```
g takes w,h
let j be 0
while j is less than h
let i be 0
while i is less than w
let c be j*w+i
let p be c-1
if i is 0
let p be c-w

if p is as high as 0    
say "("+p+"-"+c+")"

build i up

build j up
```

It can be invoked like

```
g taking 3,2
```

with the output as

```
(0-1)
(1-2)
(0-3)
(3-4)
(4-5)
```

you can also [try it online](https://codewithrockstar.com/online)!

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 49 bytes

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY7NUsIwFIV1m6c401VSGmgoKjKDjksWbmRcMSwiDW21pJgG6x9PwoaNbnwifRpL2wGduXNv8s0599zNZz6TqQy-Jg7XWSGNdqY_x0fZ3b2aWVzLROONAKGaY1F-qDRRPsCVMfJlMrYm0dGUDXCrE4thpQSeZIoiCW1ckt6exCqJ4p0o2COj8lW6Q5HSykirbqSOVE4rs9c4WCVflkk21bS2tBcPdTZ1qkuo46Ep5rCdY01InfF_9QCUjrT1UDY2vBjpUD2rcKweJwc8ZeVFHys75_1vQQsvLoWU-rAZCt5lrVbzdmMuGGu_JksqDqAxXq5JxyU-54LzLucBeQeaIj3gBDgFzv7SPnAOCB9CELdTr9lu6_kL)

```scala
(w,h)=>((0 to w-2)++(0 to w*h-1)).zip(1 to w*h-1)
```

The output `IndexedSeq[(Int, Int)])` is corresponding to a spanning tree like this (for w=4, h=3):

```
0--1--2--3
|  |  |  |
4  5  6  7
|  |  |  |
8  9  10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 68 bytes

Takes input as `(w)(h)`. Prints pairs of 0-based numbered vertices.

```javascript
w=>g=(h,n=0,p=n)=>((n/w&1?n--:++n)%w?n:n=p+w)<w*h&&g(h,n,print(p,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcvNCsIwEATgu08hBcOuSdC0DUjrti/ipQj98bCEWpq8faxY/LsN883cmrm5X8fBTXo@xZaip6oj6BXTUTlipAqAD16YmrUupGTc@ZoLJic9nv2@F6J7zpUbB57AKUaMr5zkISsSLLct5AgZlpu1v3D6lvRPTLCrGAT7LTaYVSwu@PMxn88i8QE)

Recursively creates the following pattern (here with \$w=4\$):

```
 0→ 1→ 2→ 3
          ↓
 4← 5← 6← 7
 ↓
 8→ 9→10→11
          ↓
   … ←14←15
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
×ḶsUÐeFṡ2
```

Explanation:

```
×ḶsUÐeFṡ2 the main and only link, takes the dimensions as input
×         multiply the dimensions
 Ḷ        create the range of 0..h*w-1
  s       split into chunks of length w, I have no idea how does this part refer to w
    Ðe    at even indices
   U      reverse the chunks
      F   flatten
       ṡ2 split in overlapping slices of length 2 (path -> edge list)
```

The tree is actually a snake-like path:

```
01234
98765
ABCDE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//w5fhuLZzVcOQZUbhuaEy////NP8z)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＦ×θη¿ιＩ⟦⎇﹪ιθ⊖ι⁻ιθι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcuxCsIwEIDh3ae48Q7iomNHXRwqDt3EIaZXcpAm5pIIPn0suDh@/PzOW3XJht4v8dXqta1PVsw07P7tNy9JASdZuWA24IlAFkAhuKnEiidbKt4n1mj1g2OaW0goBjIZOLNTXjlWnrfBwCixlV/cJA@iofcDHPv@Hb4) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs using the following format:

```
0-1
|
2-3
|
4-5
```

Alternative solution, also 22 bytes:

```
ＮθＮηＦ×θη¿ιＩ⟦⎇‹ιθ⊖ι⁻ιθι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqhDgIxDIBhz1NUtskwIE@CIQGCOEcQY/SyJrfdrdtIePoxgUB@@X/nrbrFzq2d4lrLtYYnKyYaNv/23dOigKMEzpgMeCKQCVAIbiqx4MHmgveRNVr94JlzRjGQyMCRnXLgWPjVdwMXifUXu@RBNLS2g33bvucv) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs using the following format:

```
0-1
| |
2 3
| |
4 5
```

Bonus version:

```
ＮθＦＮＦθ«Ｊ⊗κ⊗ι¿∧κ∨¬ι‽←+-↑✂+|⁰⊕ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCsIwFETX7VdcskpoCtWlrgQ3Fani4wP6uMVgHm1M3KjfHqNScDec4cy0l9q2ppYhlHrwrvKqQUtHtkx7Y4H@Q8bgy0YGjzTZeDWcDF0b30js6JVxmLJgUU9ED3SlY8NhZ2llXOQcDrXujIpbcW1vhXZ0scXecSBZTj4ayhtOzXngcJSiRUqyJ@FQcCh1a1Ghdr@faLxCmBcwK0J@l28) Link is to verbose version of code.