# Given a list of strings, find all elements which are still in the list when any character is deleted

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

Write a program using the fewest bytes of source code which given a list of strings finds all elements which are still in the list when any character is deleted.

For example, given a list of all English words `boats` would be output because `oats`, `bats`, `bots`, `boas`, `boat` are all English words and thus would be in the list.

Simple Pyhon code example, assuming `words` is the input list:

```
for w in words:
    has_all = True
    for i in range(len(w)):
        test = w[:i] + w[i+1:]
        if test not in words:
            has_all = False
            break
    if has_all
        print(w)
```

Example input list with some strings:

```
aorn (+)
aor (+)
arn
aon
orn (+)
ao
ar
or
rn
on
```

The strings marked with `(+)` are the ones that should be the output.

`arn` and `aon` shouldn't be output because we can delete the middle character to get `an`, which is not in the input list.

You should test that aba is not present on the output of this list:

```
aba
ba
aa
b
```

Comment: I would not recommend to copy-paste a large dictionary in the challenge. But I think you should include a test dictionary (say ~100 words) so that the solutions can be easily tested.

Comment: Edited with a small list of examples. Added `code-golf` tag.

Comment: "when any character is deleted" -> then "arn" and "aon" should be positive I think, you remove "a" or "n" and it's in the list.. or are the first and last char not removeable? in that case should't say "any"

Comment: @Kaddath when `r` is removed from `arn`, the result is `an`, which is not in the list. It should be possible to remove *any* character, not just one of them.

Comment: Might the input have repeated characters?

Comment: Yes, repeated characters are allowed. Indeed most English examples I am aware of have repeated characters.

Comment: Nice first question!  Could I ask you to repeat the information of the title, as well as the relevant bits from [tag:code-golf] into the body of the question?  It is how most challenges are written here so it makes this easier to read.  In addition the code-golf tag has important rules that can be easily missed by newcomers since they require clicking on a specific element to be found.  Thanks.

Comment: I have added the requested bits.

Comment: I think you should add some test cases with repeat characters like `["aba","ab","aa","b"]` to catch solutions that try remove every copy of a character, or always remove the first copy. Having more test cases is good in general.

Comment: Are we really supposed to support 1-character words? If yes, are we also supposed to support the empty string, which would make 1-character words valid? (cc @xnor)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
*/@e.~1<\.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/tfQdUvXqDG1i9GL/a3JxpWQml9jqKdhY68UbAlWn5Csk5SRmKCQllhQrJOWDiUQwUaKQDxKryixQ5@JKTc7IVwBpVUhTUAdJFqujilVUVKj/BwA)

J's "outfix" adverb `\.` does exactly what we need here.

Take the dictionary as the left arg (implicitly, via the overall dyadic hook), and the string to test as the right arg.

- `1<\.]` Returns the box of every length 1 outfix of our right arg, that is, every copy with exactly 1 char deleted.
- `e.~` Asks if each of those is an element of the dictionary given  as the left arg. Returns a list of boolean zeros and ones.
- `*/@` Multiplies them all together, that is, are they all one?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda L:[w for w in L if{w[:i]+w[i+1:]for i in range(len(w))}<={*L}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUcHHKrpcIS2/SKFcITNPwUchM626PNoqM1a7PDpT29AqFiSVCZIqSsxLT9XISc3TKNfUrLWxrdbyqY397@MZHGIbrZ6Un1hSrK4DoqEUkISKASmIEJiCkRBlMEo9lqugKDOvRCNNA2SipuZ/AA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 71 bytes

```python
lambda L:[w for w in L if{w[:i]+w[i+1:]for i in range(len(w))}<=set(L)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUcHHKrpcIS2/SKFcITNPwUchM626PNoqM1a7PDpT29AqFiSVCZIqSsxLT9XISc3TKNfUrLWxLU4t0fDRjP3v4xkcYhutnpSfWFKsrgOioRSQhIoBKYgQmIKREGUwSj2Wq6AoM69EIU0DZKLmfwA)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.filter(w=>[...w].every((_,i)=>a.includes(w.slice(0,i)+w.slice(i+1))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxhCoMwDEaPY0QX5gHqRURGqenIKO1oncXTd2nR/PiS7z3IRx86mcjf/eHDRsWqotWs0bLbKUJW84KIeUU6KJ4Ar5H76tkb99soQcbk2BA8RQx34WHqZYoJPgVH6MIbLCydDtF3Y101r7vmzRtuXaIx0at8@gM)

---

#### 75 bytes

A bit more fun, but 1 byte longer:

```javascript
a=>a.filter(w=>w.replace(/./g,"$`$',").split`,`.every(w=>!w|a.includes(w)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxhCsMgDEbPslJQwaUnsBcZgwYbi0O0qKsUdvdOZfvzkrzvIy88MOlo93z3YaXLqAvVjGCsyxR5UXOBSLtDTXyCaZPDuIxMDgLS7mxe5AJ0UDxb81Y@CNZr914p8SKEuHTwKTgCFzZu@INhiJ7JNhp/e@Pfd93viu5q/Kyfvg)

or:

```javascript
a=>a.filter(w=>!+w.replace(/./g,_=>+!a.includes(r["$`"]+r["$'"])),r=RegExp)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDsIgEEXP0sakNEV6ArrzAm6bRid02qAIZKhWT49AdPP@/PeTucELgiLtt2PwekZ6OHvHT1xkBDmAWLTZkNguh6rbBaE3oJD1ol/5RQ5dBUJbZZ4zBkZjfbjWU5ezqae25STPuJ7evo3K2eAMCuNWtrCxAUe24Tkyf3fm3xddekJxaU4/4xc) (SpiderMonkey)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
e-ƤẠ¥Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9V99iSh7sWHFp6rP3/w91bDrdH/v@fmF@UxwUkuBLBdB4XhA/kAllcQHZ@HgA)

A monadic link taking a list of words and returning a list of words.

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving a byte!

### Explanation

```
    ¥Ƈ | Keep only those where the following is true:
e-Ƥ    | - Check whether each outfix with sublists length 1 removed is in the original list
   Ạ   | - All
```

Comment: Save a byte using *exists in* with `e-ƤP¥Ƈ` - [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9V99iSgENLj7X/P9zu/f9/tHpiflGeug6IApFQNoiEiYOFwXwgARYDSscCAA) (`P` can  of course be `Ạ`)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 45 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.reject{|i|i.gsub(/./m){[$`+$']-a}[?"]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlGvKDUrNbmkuiazJlMvvbg0SUNfTz9XszpaJUFbRT1WN7E22l4ptrb2f4FCWnS0elJ@Ykmxug6IhlJAEioGpCBCYApGQpTBKPXY2P8A)

For each character in a string, generate the string with it deleted, then replace the character with either that string, if it's not in `a`, or an empty array, using `-` for the set complement operation. Then check whether the result contains any string representations.

Edit: -3 bytes from Value Ink by not converting arrays to booleans.

Comment: This is _incredible_

Comment: [45 bytes -- use `[$\`+$']-a` and check if the string contains a `"` instead.](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOlGvKDUrNbmkuiazJlMvvbg0SUNfTz9XszpaJUFbRT1WN7E22l4ptrb2f4FCWnS0elJ@Ykmxug6IhlJAEioGpCBCYApGQpTBKPXY2P8A "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 34 bytes

```
~:a{.,,{1$.2$<\@)>+a?)}%{and}*\;},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v84qsVpPR6faUEXPSMUmxkHTTjvRXrNWtToxL6VWK8a6Vud/bML/aKXE/KI8JQUQBSKhbBAJEwcLg/lAAiwGlI4FAA)

## Explanation

```
~   # Evaluate the inplicit list input
 :a # Assign to the variable a w/o popping
    # (To be golfed)
{                           }, # Huge filter block
 .   # Copy the current string
  ,, # Generate a length list
    {                 }% # Map the length list:
     1$.2$<\@)>+      # Remove the character at the index
                a?)   # Is this string still in the list?
    {and}*               # logical AND all of the results
    \;                # Discard the extra operand
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Φθ⬤ι№θΦι⁻ξμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMtM6cktUijUEfBMSdHI1NHwTm/FCgM5ENlgEK@mXmlxRoVOgq5mmBg/f9/dLRSYn5RnpKOAogGUzAemILLQaQgQiASIg5UFBv7X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 θ          Input array
Φ           Filter where
   ι        Current word
  ⬤         All characters satisfy
    №       (Non-zero) Count of
       ι    Current word
      Φ     Filtered where
         ξ  Character index
          μ Inner index
        ⁻   Differ (i.e. filter out that character index)
     θ      In input array
            Implicitly output each matching word on its own line
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.select{|w|(1..w.size).all?{|a|l&[w[0,a-1]+w[a..-1]]!=[]}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkevODUnNbmkuqa8RsNQT69crzizKlVTLzEnx766JrEmRy26PNpAJ1HXMFa7PDpRTw/IiFW0jY6tra39X6CQFh2tnpSfWFKsrgOioRSQhIoBKYgQmIKREGUwSj029j8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 112 bytes

```php
for(;$s=$argv[++$i];$j=0){for($t=1;$s[$j];)$t&=in_array(substr($s,0,$j).substr($s,++$j),$argv);if($t)echo"$s,";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzRCsIwDEX/ZQRZWBnzuRY/ZAyJ4lz70Ja0CjL89pjNB19u7uGGk5csp3PWnBO3FooD4sdr7Drwk4XgBly3Bao76jpCmCxCPTgfL8RM77Y8r6XqQzGDgYD9n9UR0Ow@tH5WB95vS2p0auxHRChx3EJov1F@rKhNtKf4BQ)

That's still pretty ugly and throws a lot of notices, but it works..

Pretty straightforward:

```php
for(;$s=$argv[++$i];$j=0){ //loops on arguments skipping the first (script name) and resetting $j each turn
  for($t=1;$s[$j];)        //loops on all chars indexes initializing $t to true
    $t&=in_array(substr($s,0,$j).substr($s,++$j),$argv); //checks if in arguments array, with deleted char -> bitwise AND the result to $t
  if($t)echo"$s,";         //if $t still true, displays argument with a coma
}
```

caveat: can lead to false positive if the name of the script is a word that can be a match in the list (".code.tio" in TIO, so OK here)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzbCoMwEET/RRZxMRR93gY/RKSsxUvyUEMSBSn99u22L8IwMJzhhDXIvQva8xYrgmSB43L0dQ1uIPC2wfePQLat0h78QAi5tO714Bj5rNI@pqyHZBoDHm/XVodH8/chuVkdOD3XrVBU0EdEeGTRsPYX) for the added second test case `[aba, ba, aa, b]`

EDIT: saved 3 bytes using bitwise assign operator `&=in_array` instead of logical operator `=$t&&in_array`

EDIT2: saved another 3 by initializing `$j` to zero and moving `++` inside `substr`

EDIT3: saved another one by resetting `$j` to zero in first loop declaration, saving the `,` (it is undefined on first iteration, causing a bunch of new notices, but PHP is a smart guy)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 67 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Where(x=>x.Select((y,_)=>x.Remove(_,1)).All(y=>a.Contains(y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3NCsIwEITP5ikWT7tQC55rCyIKggfRg8cSw9YG0hST@FNKn71ai@Jlh/lmd1b5mfK639ysWuy0DwsfnLaXLNqu7a1iJ8@Gvywr0l6mmYxPJTvGZ5o94yMbVgGxiXIa/IGr@s6YR3OieGkMNsPBqrZBauuxIaI@Ef@fwEAKlh/wD5HaqaydnUYw6Ee@7iO/bIxGNMyRv5e6RIiidixViWMrXEFbKNAQQSsm@zcLeKVEdP0L)

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, <s>137</s> <s>130</s> 121 bytes

```java
L->L.stream().filter(w->{var b=1>0;for(int i=0;i<w.length();)b&=L.contains(w.substring(0,i)+w.substring(++i));return b;})
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@ExpiredData*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZHBbsIwDIbvPIXVw5SoELHrSivtOKljB47TDmlXWFhJUeJSIcSzd04axoBx8Z/Y1u8v8Vru5GT9@d2XtbQWXqXShxGA0liZpSwrmLsrwJr6RIuqFhZNJTdi4WVGovQqg5KdO3Jl8beQ84QMjiMKFiWqEuagIYU@n2R5MGNcLFVNE1k3yQ47aaBIH7NpsmwMIxJQ6TRRs07UlV7hF@MJLx7SXJSNRuK1rBO2LawfyKZjxeO/iThWnCemwtZoKJIj7xMHs22LmmAC065Rn7AhMzZwv3@A5MPLsbLIItkYHY2duBjOLp7yPu3vFHyOyv7tJ4uikWhdfpAiSBNEBsHo5sc8nTcZ6IQQtKFtiwFxsbdYbUTTothSHWvNohdXfwKI4vNino2ReyuwGWzY4BEgr9oulljThXamq@7ftozdzJDWVS4nXGOy6K1FTxnd6aCH3KfXomQOjFPK1xjn933Cpx77Hw)

**Explanation:**

```java
L->                      // Method with String-List parameter & String-Stream return-type
  L.stream().filter(w->  //  Filter the words in the input-Stream by:
    var b=1>0;           //   Create a boolean, starting at true
    for(int i=0;i<w.length();)
                         //   Loop `i` in the range [0, word-length)
      b&=                //    Check if all are truthy for:
         L.contains(w.substring(0,i)+w.substring(++i)
                         //     Remove the `i`th character from the word
                      ); //     and check if this is in the input-list
    return b;})          //   And return the resulting boolean
```

Comment: [130 using streams?](https://tio.run/##dVJNb8IwDL3zK6KcEgHRdh1bpR2RCjtwnHZwS4CwkKLGZaomfnvnpGEMGD341R99fra7hQOMt8vPrrTgPZuBcd8DxoxDXa@g1GweXMa2VKcaNFZ5rDXs1CLCM4Fx64yV4lyRG4@/iVxOiOA4IOMR0JRszhx7YV0@zvJEJqRaGUsdBYyzm05Th30zVYNba/EwAmW1W@NGSKnA2hlguRFt4CsrhzSCF6B8U/iogT5o5fBvoB0@Snq6SVC1bwpLqpK4Q2WWbEcUoh/g/YOB7FeA2qPgUNWOjwIEm96DPcVjOPpkYozScQkniqIC9CHeQ5GgSgAJkN@sLqqLJL06pRSdat9gkrhoPeqdqhpUe8qjdYJPQ/6JMT48b/a1rqH1CqueRvQcSeRV2cU1LTl0PKe//i3LxE0P8CFz2eFapuBvDUaV/E4FDXJfvVOlCMIkhWKO/ov7PGmpx@4H "Java (JDK) – Try It Online") bare in mind I'm not good at java - so probably golfable

Comment: @ExpiredData Ah, didn't realize that ended up being shorter. I indeed had that approach in my head as well after seeing the JS, C#, and 05AB1E answers using a filter, but figured it would be too long due to the `java.util.stream.IntStream.range(0,a.length())` being so long, so didn't bother trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>216</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>164</s></sup> 160 bytes

```cpp
#import<string>
#import<set>
void f(std::set<std::string>d){for(auto w:d){int h=1,i=0;for(;w[i]*h;){auto t=w;h=d.find(t.erase(i++,1))!=end(d);}h&&puts(&w[0]);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/LDoIwEEX3/YqqCWkFDW6p5UeMi8YWmURaUgZZEL4diw/QxK7OvXOaaS91vbvclL2O4waq2nk8NujBXnMyZ4M5uTvQtGAN6iwLxfEFL1PzvnCeqRYd7bKQwCIt5SEBmYppIroTnLel4P3TQdmJUup9AVYz3BuvGsMgjpMD5ytpQqm5GMooqltsWNSd0nPIw/h3OdW0JzSctXLerpOZZ/xuZ/xxF3UZf2jxwmUyCDJ9rlJgGX8vLqbnPskbbL2lqSADGR8)

Saved 10 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

**Ungolfed:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

void f(const std::set<std::string>& words) {
    for (auto word : words) {
        bool hit = true;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
            auto temp = word;
            temp.erase(i, 1);
            if (words.find(temp) == end(words)) {
                hit = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (hit) {
            std::cout << word << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## AWK, <s>101</s> 94 bytes

```
{a[$0]++}END{for(w in a){e=split(w,x,"");for(i in x){t=w;sub(x[i],"",t);e*=a[t]}if(e)print w}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYmxCsMgFEV3v0JCB20cuotbu/YHxOEVDDxaNBjLE8RvNyZZ7j2HA/TtvYK9Pdw8t9f7WZeYBHEMHGT1Zlt/mAWpoqZJ6qPh0Yqs2ZDe/h9RLLoRVZba3w3Y7Bouwss1YcicWusdYgpsDIPzA7t86CA2OIYd)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell 42 bytes

```hs
f l=[e|e<-l,all(\c->filter(/=c)e`elem`l)e]
```

In `f` I'm just literally asking for all elementes `e` in the list `l`, such that, for all characters `c` in that element, if I filter `c` from `e` (`filter(/=c)e`), the result is still in the list (`` filter(/=c)e`elem`l ``).

Comment: What if a string has repeated characters? Won't this remove all instances of that character rather than just one?

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-f`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I am *horribly* out of practice; (now slightly less) convinced this can be shorter!

```
¬e@NÎøUjY
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWY&code=rGVATs74VWpZ&input=WyJhb3JuIiwiYW9yIiwiYXJuIiwiYW9uIiwib3JuIiwiYW8iLCJhciIsIm9yIiwicm4iLCJvbiJd)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

<sup>*[crossed out 44 is still 44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195414/76162)*</sup>

```perl6
{@^a.grep:{m:ex/^(.*).(.*)$/>>.join⊂@a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv9ohLlEvvSi1wKo61yq1Qj9OQ09LUw9EqOjb2ell5WfmPepqckisrf1fnFipkKaQk5mXWvw/Mb8ojwtIcCWC6TwuCB/IBbK4gOz8PAA)

Filter from the input list elements where the possible regex matches excluding one letter are a subset of the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
ʒæ¤g<ùåP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//1KTDyw4tSbc5vPPw0oD//6OVEvOL8pR0FEA0mILxwBRcDiIFEQKREHGgolgA)

```
ʒ            # filter the list of words by:
 æ           #  powerset of the word
  ¤g<        #  length of the word - 1
     ù       #  elements of the powerset that have this length
      åP     #  are they all in the list of words?
```

Comment: @downvoter care to explain what’s wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 58 bytes

```sh
for x;(repeat $#x (($@[(I)$x[0,i]${x: ++i}]))||exit;<<<$x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYcxDsIwDEX3nMISHmwVpM40AytnqDoYKVGzJCjNYEE5e3BB@nr/vde29khMbgsNLtpjqaAT1fAM0gBPCkR4m@nOqPN4Tgu@9QrDkD4L874HTW3y3qNyZ@ciyEPAJsajSs0HQH6f4d@WZmBecv8C)

I abuse a `(subshell)` to remove the need to reset `i` on each iteration, and to use `exit` instead of `continue 2`.

```sh
for x;(repeat $#x (($@[(I)$x[0,i]${x: ++i}]))||exit;<<<$x)
for x;                                                      # for each element
      (repeat $#x                                  ;     )  # repeat for the length
      (                   $x[0,i]${x: ++i}               )  # 1-indexed substring, zero-indexed substring
      (             $@[(I)                ]              )  # get smallest index of match
      (           ((                       ))||exit;     )  # if zero, exit the subshell
      (                                             <<<$x)  # if we didn't exit, print the string
      (                                                  )  # exit subshell, which unsets i.
```