# just a caesar cipher... with a twist

Tags: code-golf, alphabet, cryptography, text-processing

I have been going to [puzzling.se](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), and people over there write stuff in rot13 a lot, sot this gave me an idea:
Write a program that takes 2 inputs, a string and integer:

1. the message to encode or decode
2. how far to shift

You can input in a function call, and output in any legal way
twist:
it **must** work with any printable ascii character.
Example code:

```python
def ceasar_cipher(message,shift):
    o = ""
    for n in message:
        o+=(chr(ord(n)+shift))
    return o
```

python 3 examples:

input:

> ceasar_cipher(“hello, world”,13):

output:

> "uryy|9-\x84|\x7fyq."

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.
The output should be a string
-Can raise an error if it will go past ASCII-characters, or just not shift said characters
Good luck!

Comment: *You can input in a function call, and output in any legal way twist:
it must work with any printable ascii character, meaning that it will still shift by the same shift as everything else.* Get quite lost here. Could you please rewrite this more clearly. Also competitions of this sort usually don't have to handle input errors.

Comment: What happens if the shift puts us past the largest character value, or a negative shift puts the character value below zero? Do we wrap around? The example code doesn't handle this.

Comment: @xnor you may raise an error, or just not shift it.

Comment: @pyton Thanks, you should add this info it's the challenge.

Answer (score 9):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 1 byte

Anonymous tacit infix function. Order of arguments doesn't matter.

```
+
```

[Try BQN!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkCsKImhlbGxvLCB3b3JsZCIgRiAxMw==)

Comment: was BQN made for this?

Comment: @pyton Not at all. Read the explanation [here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/types.html#characters).

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>4</s> 3 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/195414/94066)</sup>

*-1 byte thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen).*

```python
Ç+ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cLv24eX//2ek5uTk6yiU5xflpHAZGgMA)

```python
Ç+ç  # full program
 +   # increment...
Ç    # charcodes of...
     # implicit input
 +   # by...
     # implicit input
  ç  # convert to chars
     # implicit output
```

Comment: It's fine to leave the `J` out and just output as a list of characters. A string is a sequence of characters in most languages anyway, so when a string is asked you're also allowed to output as a list/array/stream of characters instead of an actual string.

Answer (score 4):

## [K](https://aplwiki.com/k), 4 bytes

Anonymous tacit function taking two arguments in any order.

```
`c$+
```

[Try K!](https://kparc.io/kc/#f%3A%60c%24%2B%3Bf%5B13%3B%22hello%2C%20world%22%5D)

`+` add the arguments (this implicitly converts the characters to code points

…`$` cast to…

`` `c `` character

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 32 bytes

```c
f(s,n)char*s;{for(;*s;*s+++=n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJtT8IwEP7Or7g0gbRsi@BLfJnoB@OvoMZgaWFxFmxHLML@uvPWDhjKkm338jz39O4qkpkQVaWojTUT84np23SjFoamaPRtFEUjzdKyWppMF9QDII8hGJLBpgP4YA4MjGCYehf5QOtYhrFBir97sIXJpaY5gwRhEEXZjlw/vryiNLNBKB9nL@yRdAW5I5y7riMsrmO9gVOKpXteLWqg1wPPgNEIZM0MgNJ/jSxWRoNJO2XnY5JputMNPRTSFq92jFzYkLnM80UMXwuTTy0p0784HXDDi6OUdEspCjn1SayyMuv19jbh7uZyy921Wn8elxJzKd6laTS5ez7n7vYJ3ysSQ9u/2PEOA9VT6ZqhehMHm33LhaKhD3bWuP3G95Ouke1phz1jmaZ5D3g5TLVW0ru0/peu6fC2UuNmp5ZFw1Yao2K5pgiIwbZ2pUJIt0LN2gknXcux@e4UkgfgBE17jPRHlnim/bBPHVogIFwgLyVPSgFqaRLv1yAO96WsfoTKJzNbJV@/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode@#+#2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277360oP9c5I7EoMbkktcg5PyU1OiQfhe@grK1sFKv2P6AoM69EwSE9WikjNScnX0ehPL8oJ0VJR8HQOPb/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `s`,  3 bytes

```
C+C
```

### Explained

```
C     # Convert input string to a list of ord values
 +    # Add implicit number shift
  C   # Convert back to a list of chars and output
```

If it must absolutely be a function:

## 7 bytes

```
λ2|C+C;
```

### Explained

```
λ2|C+C;
λ2|      # Start a lambda with two arguments
   C+C   # Same as the full program
      ;  # Close lambda
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 bytes

```
{n+m
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7Bn%2Bm&i=13,%22hello,+world%22)

a downside of `m` printing stuff with newline is that you need an explicit bracket.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
O+Ọ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99f@@Hunv///2cAufk6CuX5RTkp/w2NAQ)

### Explanation

```
O+Ọ  Main Link
O    chr->ord of left argument
 +   add (left with right; implicit vectorization)
  Ọ  ord->chr of left argument
```

Comment: I don't like the way this looks at me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
⭆η℅⁺Ｉθ℅ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaGToKDgDJROTS1KLNAJySos1nBOLSzQKNXUU/ItSMvMSczQyNUHA@v9/Q2OujNScnHwdhfL8opyU/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 η          Second input
⭆           Map over characters and join
       ι    Current character
      ℅     Ordinal
   ⁺        Plus
     θ      First input
    Ｉ       Cast to integer
  ℅         Character
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 18 bytes

```
"$+"+T` -þ`!-ÿ
0A`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0lFW0k7JEFB9/C@BEXdw/u5DBwT/v83NObKSM3JyddRKM8vykkBAA) Works on all ISO-8859-1 characters as long as the result does not exceed U+00FF. Add 2 bytes to extend the output range to U+07FF. Add a further 2 bytes to extend the output range to UCS-2 characters up to U+FFFF. Explanation:

```
"$+"+`
```

Repeat the given number of times.

```
T` -þ`!-ÿ
```

Bump all the supported code points up by 1.

```
0A`
```

Delete the count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
mȯc+⁰c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fE@mTtR40bkv///2/yvyQjVaGwNDM5WyGpKL88TyEtv0IhqzS3oFghvyy1SAEknZNYVamQkp8OAA)

```
m       # map over each element in arg 2
 ȯ      # 3 functions:
     c  # convert character to value
   +⁰   # add arg 1
  c     # convert back to character
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby 2.7](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```ruby
->w,s{w.bytes.map{(_1+s).chr}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf165cp7i6XC@psiS1WC83saC6JqlGI0m7WFMvOaOotvZ/gUJatHpGak5Ovo5CeX5RToq6joKhcex/AA)

Returns an array of chars. TIO uses an older version of Ruby, whereas in Ruby 2.7, we've numbered parameters, which saves two bytes.