# Color RGB int to hex

Tags: code-golf

Given three integers rgb, output hexadecimal representation as a string.

```
Input:          Output:
72 61 139       #483D8B
75 0 130        #4B0082
0 255 127       #00FF7F
```

Shortest most unorthodox code wins

Comment: Our FAQ says [All questions on this site... should have an objective primary winning criterion, so that it is possible to indisputably decide which entry should win.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Shortest is objective, but "most unorthodox" is not. Also, the [tag:code-golf] tag should be used only if the winning condition is just the shortest code; and the [tag:code-challenge] tag should be used only if the [tag:code-golf] tag isn't.

Comment: and accept the winner before some time (in this case, wasn't even 24h) kind of discourages further contributions...

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sorry I will make sure to read the guidlines from now on :( I guess you are right unorthodox is very vague

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Ruby: 19 characters

```ruby
$_=?#+"%02X"*3%$F
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ ruby -pae '$_=?#+"%02X"*3%$F' <<< '72 61 139'
#483D8B

bash-4.1$ ruby -pae '$_=?#+"%02X"*3%$F' <<< '75 0 130'
#4B0082

bash-4.1$ ruby -pae '$_=?#+"%02X"*3%$F' <<< '0 255 127'
#00FF7F
```

Answer (score 18):

### Ruby

I was going more for the "unorthodox" part. ;)

```
10;a=    gets.   split
.  map  {|       x|  #x
"%02X"  %(  x.   to_i)
}; $>   <<   ?#  <<  a[
00  ..   1+2].   join;
```

The font (on my web browser) is a bit tall, so it looks distorted, but it looks better in Courier New:

[image]

Sample run:

```
c:\a\ruby>rgb2hex
255 100 0
#FF6400
```

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 6):

## q/k (3 chars)

Not exactly unorthodox but quite short

```
4h$
```

Example

```
q)4h$ 72 61 139
0x483d8b
```

To match the output format in the question exactly, we can do (for 9 chars):

```
"#",/$4h$
```

Comment: This is missing the pound sign (#) required per the sample outputs in the question.

Answer (score 5):

#### bash <s>22</s> 21 chars

(Thanks @manatwork for 1 char using `\` instead of double-quotes)

```
printf \#%02X%02X%02X 12 12 12 
#0C0C0C
```

or reading *STDIN* in a loop: 48 chars:

```
while read f;do printf "#%02X%02X%02X\n" $f;done <<<$'72 61 139\n75 0 130\n0 255 127'
#483D8B
#4B0082
#00FF7F
```

#### Added 2015-10-06:  bash (more *unorthodox* method) <s>84</s> 83 chars

```
c=({0..9} {a..f}) d=\#;for b;do for a in / %;do d+=${c[$b$a 020]};done;done;echo $d
```

I know, it could be 82 chars if `020` where written `16`, but I prefer this... Or maybe `d+=${c[$b$a 0x10]}` which was first post.

```
hexcolor() {
    local a b c=({0..9} {a..f}) d=\#
    for b ;do
        for a in / % ;do
            d+=${c[$b$a 0x10]}
        done
    done
    echo $d
}
hexcolor 72 61 139
#483d8b
hexcolor 75 0 130
#4b0082
hexcolor 0 255 127
#00ff7f
```

#### Another [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) approach

```
#!/bin/bash
browser=firefox   #  google-chrome iceweasel
url="data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,<html><head></head><body>"
url+="<script type='text/javascript'>
  function h(i){var h=i.toString(16);if(16>1*i)h='0'+h;
  return h};function C(r,g,b){return'\043'+h(r)+h(g)+h(b)};
  function m(){ var r=1.0*R.value; var g=1.0*G.value; var b=1.0*B.value;
   var fore='black';if(384>r+g+b)fore='white';var c=C(r,g,b);
   s.setAttribute('style','background:'+c+';color:'+fore+';');s.innerHTML=c};
  function w(e){console.log(e);var val=e.target.value;var q=1;if(e.shiftKey)
  q=15;if(e.detail){if(e.detail>0){q=0-q;}}else if(0>e.wheelDelta){q=0-q;};
  val=1*val+q;if(val>255)val=255;if(0>val)val=0;e.target.value=val;m(); };
  function k(e){console.log(e);var val=e.target.value;var q=1;if(e.shiftKey)q=
  15;if(e.keyCode==38){val=1*val+q;if(val>255)val=255;e.target.value=val;m();}
  else if(e.keyCode==40){val=1*val-q;if(0>val)val=0;e.target.value=val;m();}};
  function n(){R=document.getElementById('R');G=document.getElementById('G');
    B=document.getElementById('B');s=document.getElementById('s');
    R.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',w);R.addEventListener('mousewheel',w);
    G.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',w);G.addEventListener('mousewheel',w);
    B.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll',w);B.addEventListener('mousewheel',w);
  m();};var R, G, B, s;window.onload=n;
  </script><style>div{display:inline-block;width:10em;}</style>
  <div id='s'>&nbsp;</div>"
input="%s:<input type='text' size='5' value='200'"
input+=" onKeyDown='k(event)' onChange='m()' id='%s' />"
for c in R G B ;do
    printf -v add "$input" $c $c
    url+="$add"
  done    
$browser "$url"
```

This will display a browser window, with:

[image: RGB int 2 hex viewer converter]

Where you could roll the mousewheel to change values (with shift key holded for step by 15)...

Comment: Actually the terminating newline was not requested and only “#” needs escaping, so `printf \#%02X%02X%02X` is enough.

Comment: Added a ***more unorthodox method*** :

Comment: Lol. That inner loop is indeed shockingly unorthodox.

Comment: @manatwork thanks, I find `d+=${c[$b$a 0x10]}` something *sexy*!

Comment: ... or maybe `d+=${c[$b$a 020]}` will do the job **and** look nice

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell: <strike>71</strike> <strike>52</strike> <strike>51</strike> 41

> Thanks to @manatwork for pointing out `ForEach-Object` can be used in place of a `for` loop.
>   Thanks to @Joey for pointing out that I could use `-join` on the loop output, instead of having to put it into variables.

**Golfed code:**

```
'#'+-join(1..3|%{"{0:X2}"-f+(read-host)})
```

**Note:**

There's no error checking here for invalid inputs. The script will happily take 256, 4096, and 65536 as inputs, then output #100100010000 (which obviously won't work as RGB).

**Ungolfed, with comments:**

```
# Put a hashtag in front of the output.
'#'+

# Join the nested code into one string.
-join(

    # Pipe 1..3 to ForEach-Object to run a loop three times.
    1..3|%{

        # Take user input and format it as hex, with minimum two digits in output.
        "{0:X2}"-f+(read-host)
    }
)
```

Comment: Make the loop `foreach($i in 1,2,3)` to reduce it to 68 characters.

Comment: @manatwork I don't think that's the proper syntax for a `foreach` in PowerShell. (At least, I haven't been able to get some test runs to work.) However, using the right syntax, a built-in alias, and another PowerShell shortcut I recently discovered, I think I've got something better, shaving another 12 characters off your suggestion. `(1..3)|%{...}` (Insert bracketed statement from existing script in place of the ellipsis.) I still need to fully test this in the script, but thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: No idea whether it's the proper syntax or not, but the SS64 reference for [`foreach`](http://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) mentions it and it works for me. (No idea about the version. The one which came with Windows 7.)

Comment: @manatwork That's interesting. I'd like to dig around and figure out what's wrong with that some more (I was getting "unexpected token 'in'..." errors.) some other time. It's possible the SS64 article was written for a different version of PowerShell - I'm not sure. For now, I've confirmed that `(1..3)|%` works and brings the script down to 56 characters. I'll edit that into the answer, and definitely credit you for the idea. Thanks again!

Comment: Probably some version incompatibility. http://i.stack.imgur.com/xvTAT.png Hopefully your even shorter code will work everywhere.

Comment: @manatwork Which version are you using? `$PSVersionTable.psversion` Also, I'm not sure about compatibility for this script with 3.0. I seem to recall they changed the way variables are scoped by default, so calling `$1`, `$2`, or `$3` from outside the function in which they were created might not work without some additional code.

Comment: 2, 0, -1, -1? (Now I realize I never seen a PowerShell version number before.) http://i.stack.imgur.com/mBwvT.png

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11479/discussion-between-iszi-and-manatwork)

Comment: Apparently, in some cases, `foreach` is *not* translated as an alias to `ForEach-Object` - it's its own loop construct. http://superuser.com/a/675488/50086

Comment: I was about to comment here, but then ended up writing [my own implementation](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15300/15) after noticing that the task is fairly trivial. You can at least drop the parentheses and the 0 around the `Read-Host`. `+$foo` is the same as `(0+$foo)` (a trick I shared in [Tips for golfing in PowerShell](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/203/15), too :)). You can then drop the quotes around `$_` as well. Which then brings you down to 46.

Comment: Oh, dang. You can get this to 41 by using `-join`: `'#'+-join(1..3|%{"{0:X2}"-f+(read-host)})`.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 31 characters

```
perl -nE 'say"#",map{unpack H2,chr}split'
```

It's hard to make such a short program unorthodox, but I think this works.

Comment: I like this answer :) a few more and I think I might settle on this if nothing better rolls around.

Comment: Cool! Just an `unpack` question: can you make the hexadecimal a..f uppercase, like in the question?

Comment: @manatwork I tried to find a way to do it inside of `unpack`, but no luck. One way is to use `sprintf` instead of `unpack`, but that's longer and completely orthodox. The other way is to just modify the string to uppercase : `map{uc unpack H2,chr}`, at a cost of three characters.

Comment: Thank you, @breadbox. Those tricky little `pack` and `unpack` never get into my coding style. So its unorthodox enough for me.

Comment: Wrong count. This make 30 char!

Comment: @F.Hauri The `-n` option counts as one character, so the total is 31. The rules for counting option characters are described here: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions/274#274.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish) <s>103</s> 60

```
"#"or>1[:82*%:}-82*,86*+:"9"v
    ;^?l ]o+*7)"9":+*68o+*7)<
```

Made use of the wasted white space, and moved some code into it

Run with command line inputs:

```
python fish.py generateHex.fish -v 255 36 72
```

output:
"#FF2448"

Comment: Will provide explanation on request. If you can figure it out I'd rather not bother

Answer (score 3):

#### Perl *24* chars

```
perl -ne 'printf"#"."%02x"x3,split'
13 31 133
#0d1f85
```

Sorry, it's not as sexy than using `unpack`, but shorter!

#### More obscure version:

But if you really prefer to use `unpack`, then you could:

```
$==24;s/\d+[\n ]*/{$=-=8;($&<<$=).do{rand>.5?qw<+>[0]:"|"}}/eg;$_=
pack("N",eval($_.587.202.560));say$1,unpack("H6",$2)if/^(.)(.*)$/s
```

For sample, it's not the shorter version, but I like it! ( Note the use of `rand` for *randering* this :-)

```
perl -nE '
    $==24;s/\d+[\n ]*/{$=-=8;($&<<$=).
    do{rand>.5?qw<+>:"|"}}/eg;$_=pack(
    "N",eval($_.587.202.560) );say $1,
    unpack("H"."6",$2) if /^(.)(.*)$/s
  ' <<< $'72 61 139\n75 0 130\n0 255 127'
#483d8b
#4b0082
#00ff7f
```

Answer (score 3):

### Action Script 3 | 43 characters

```
trace("#"+(72<<16|61<<139|b).toString(16));
```

Output: `#483D8B`

Comment: Can you not drop a lot of white space here? I don't know Action Script, but they don't look required

Comment: @Cruncher yeah sorry, one of my first answers here.

Comment: Kill the semicolon at the end to save a char

Answer (score 2):

### C (67 chars no main boilerplate)

```
int r,g,b;
scanf("%d %d %d",&r,&b,&g);
printf("#%06x",r<<16|g<<8|b);
```

the bog standard printf & bit twiddler usage

Comment: Wait, `readf`? Shouldn't that be `scanf`?

Comment: @breadbox ah yeah I spent too much time in D; either way no difference in char count

Answer (score 2):

### Forth, 62 characters

```
: D 0 <<# # # #> TYPE #>> ; 35 EMIT HEX SWAP ROT D D D DECIMAL
```

Comment: doesn't work for 1 1 1 which should output #010101

Comment: Hi @ratchetfreak. It works for me. Just tested with gforth. Giving it `1 1 1` outputs `#010101`. Any other values 0-255 also work. What environment or forth are you using?

Answer (score 2):

## Dc: <s>35</s> 32 characters

```
[#]n16o?ShShSh[Lhd16/n16%n]ddxxx
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ dc -e '[#]n16o?ShShSh[Lhd16/n16%n]ddxxx' <<< '72 61 139'
#483D8B

bash-4.1$ dc -e '[#]n16o?ShShSh[Lhd16/n16%n]ddxxx' <<< '75 0 130'
#4B0082

bash-4.1$ dc -e '[#]n16o?ShShSh[Lhd16/n16%n]ddxxx' <<< '0 255 127'
#00FF7F
```

### Dc: <s>27</s> 24 characters

(But needs the input numbers on separate lines.)

```
[#]n16o[?d16/n16%n]ddxxx
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ dc -e '[#]n16o[?d16/n16%n]ddxxx' <<< $'72\n61\n139'
#483D8B

bash-4.1$ dc -e '[#]n16o[?d16/n16%n]ddxxx' <<< $'75\n0\n130'
#4B0082

bash-4.1$ dc -e '[#]n16o[?d16/n16%n]ddxxx' <<< $'0\n255\n127'
#00FF7F
```

Comment: There are not enough `dc` answers on this website.

Answer (score 2):

**JavaScript, 89 chars**

```
console.log('#' + ('00000' + eval('256*(256*(' + DEC.replace(/ /g, ')+')).toString(16)).slice(-6))
```

Converts `72 61 139` to `256*(256*(72)+61)+139` and evals it.

Comment: Nice one, but fails on the 3rd sample posted in the question.

Comment: Ah, good call. Fixed.

Comment: Using `eval('(('+DEC.replace(/ /g,'<<8)+'))` instead of `eval('256*(256*('+DEC.replace(/ /g,')+'))` let you save 5 chars!

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 45

```
'#'+-join(-split(read-host)|%{'{0:X2}'-f+$_})
```

Or, if it can be used by piping in the data, you can just use

```
'#'+-join(-split"$input"|%{'{0:X2}'-f+$_})
```

which brings it down to **42**.

Comment: Nice work! Shows I still have much to learn about golfing!

Comment: Oh, your idea with the variables was clever too; would have never crossed my mind. It just so happens that it's longer than my usual favourite: `-split` and `-join`.

Answer (score 2):

### powershell 37

saved one byte thanks to TimmyD

```
cat rgb2hex.ps1
$args|%{$o+="{0:X2}"-f[byte]$_};"#$o"
wc -c rgb2hex.ps1
38 rgb2hex.ps1
powershell -f .\rgb2hex.ps1 72 61 139
#483D8B
powershell -f .\rgb2hex.ps1 0 255 127
#00FF7F
```

Comment: You can save a couple bytes by getting rid of the `[byte]` since we're given the input as integers, and edit your output to be `"#$o"` -- that gives 31 bytes for `$args|%{$o+="{0:X2}"-f$_};"#$o"`

Comment: @TimmyD   dont know if removing [byte] works correctly in all version in a version in which i tested (iirc 2.0 in xp ) without [byte] it was not concatenating as hex but as ints ie 72 61 139 was #7261139 not #483d8b "#$o" inside quotes isnt a string literal but evaluated string nice to know  thanks comments about hex conversion will be appreciated

Comment: It's apparently a difference between PowerShell v2 and v3 -- must be something in how the corresponding .NET version handles hexadecimal conversion, but I can't find documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 16 bytes

That's it. Use the built in.

```
rgb(r,g,b,m=255)
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, <s>67</s> 73 Characters (65 Chars excluding main)

```
main(){int a,b,c;scanf("%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c);printf("#%02X%02X%02X",a,b,c);}
```

Boring C program - very orthodox.

Comment: doesn't work with a b or c smaller than 16

Comment: Changed %X to %02X.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7 (80 Characters)

```
x=lambda y: ("0"+hex(int(y))[2:])[-2:]
print "#"+''.join(map(x,input().split()))
```

I'm looking for a better way to handle the single digit hex values. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use format strings? '%02x' seems to be what everyone else has done.

Answer (score 1):

#### Befunge-98, 45 characters

Bleh, duplicated code. Oh well. Just a straightforward implementation of radix conversion.

```
"#",v
7*+,>#@&:97+/"0"+:"9"`7*+,97+%"0"+:"9"`
```

Sample run

```
% cfunge tohex.98 <<<'72 61 139'
#483D8B
% cfunge tohex.98
#75 0 130
4800820 255 127
00FF7F
```

(Note: prints '#' before reading input---the task doesn't forbid this; given three numbers on stdin it produces the right output on stdout. It also doesn't bother with newlines, and as you can see it doesn't add '#' properly when run "interactively".)

Answer (score 1):

### Game Maker Language, 175 (Error at position 81)

Prompts for 3 to 9-digit RGB. Returns hexadecimal with GML hexadecimal sign, `$`

```
d=get_string('','')if(d=='')e=""else e="00"h="0123456789ABCDEF"while(d!=''){b=d&255i=string_char_at(h,byte div 16+1)l=string_char_at(h,byte mod 16+1)e+=i+l;d=d>>8}return '$'+e
```

Make this a script. Also, compile with uninitialized variables treated as 0.

[Source](http://www.gmlscripts.com/script/dec_to_hex)

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 93 characters

```
\B=@set{x;0123456789abcdef}\#
<D>=@substring{@div{$1;16};1;$x}@substring{@mod{$1;16};1;$x}
?=
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '\B=@set{x;0123456789abcdef}\#;<D>=@substring{@div{$1;16};1;$x}@substring{@mod{$1;16};1;$x};?=' <<< '0 255 127'
#00ff7f
```

Answer (score 1):

### Burlsque, 12 bytes (10 bytes for lower-case)

If lower-case is allowed as well then 10 bytes:

```
psb6\['#+]
```

Usage:

```
blsq ) "72 61 139"psb6\['#+]
"#483d8b"
```

If you desperately need upper-case, add `ZZ`:

```
blsq ) "72 61 139"psb6\['#+]ZZ
"#483D8B"
```

If you don't receive the integers as in a string then go with:

```
blsq ) {72 61 139}b6\['#+]
"#483d8b"
```

**Explanation:**

```
ps -- parse string
b6 -- to hex
\[ -- concat
'#+] -- prepend #
```

[Try online here](http://104.167.104.168/~burlesque/burlesque.cgi?q=%7B72%2061%20139%7Db6%5C[%27%23%2B]).

**Bonus:**

To convert it back use this:

```
blsq ) "#483d8b"[-2cob6
{72 61 139}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, 28 bytes

```powershell
'#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}'-f$args
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

"#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}"-f$args
}

@(
    ,('#483D8B',72, 61, 139)
    ,('#4B0082',75,  0, 130)
    ,('#00FF7F',0 ,255, 127)
) | % {
    $e,$a = $_
    $r = &$f @a
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: #483D8B
True: #4B0082
True: #00FF7F
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript: 99 chars (<s>110</s> Thanks @manatwork):

```
function h(i){x=(i*=1).toString(16);return 16>i?"0"+x:x}function c(r,g,b){return"#"+h(r)+h(g)+h(b)}
```

#### Sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/smjs

function h(i){x=(i*=1).toString(16);return 16>i?"0"+x:x}
function c(r,g,b){return"#"+h(r)+h(g)+h(b)}

if (typeof(arguments[2]) != "undefined" )
    print(c(arguments[0],arguments[1],arguments[2]));

var line;
while (line=readline()) {
    var a=line.split(" ");
    print(c(a[0],a[1],a[2]));
};
```

#### In action:

```
rgb.js 14 15 16 <<< $'15 16 17\n16 17 18'
#0e0f10
#0f1011
#101112
```

#### JS Snippet (216)

```js
function h(i){x=(i*=1).toString(16);return 16>i?"0"+x:x}
function c([r,g,b]){return"#"+h(r)+h(g)+h(b)}
function d(){o.innerHTML="";t.value.split("\n").forEach(
function(l){o.innerHTML+=c(l.split(" "))+"<br>"; })};d()
```

```html
<textarea id="t" onkeyup="d()">72 61 139
75 0 130
0 255 127</textarea><div id="o"></div>
```

Comment: You are multiplying i by 1 twice. Better do `i*=1` once. And choose a different name for the local variable, so you can leave out the `var` keyword. I don't have `smjs`, but `function h(i){x=(i*=1).toString(16);return 16>i?"0"+x:x}function c(r,g,b){return"#"+h(r)+h(g)+h(b)}` should do the same in 99 characters.

Comment: @manatwork `smjs` is the *binary* tool from [spidermonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey), also available as standard Debian packakge.

Comment: Oops. Actually I know+use+enjoy that interpreter, but I always met it with then name `js`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3.3 @ 60 chars

```
print("#"+3*"%.2X"%tuple(int(n) for n in input().split()))
```

Couldn't resist:

```
[dan@danbook:code_golf/int_to_hex]$ python3.3 int_to_hex.py
176 11 30
#B00B1E
```

Answer (score 0):

## javascript (ES6), 55

```
alert('#'+(r<<16|g<<8|b).toString(16).padStart(6,'0'))
```

Comment: You may want to place a `#` before your language name and byte count to make it a header. Also, is this ES6?

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure 76 Characters

This might be late, for the sake of completeness:

```
(defn hexy [r g b] (reduce str (cons "#" (map #(format "%02X" %) [r g b]))))
```

Example calls:

```
(hexy 0 255 127)
"#00FF7F"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 40 characters

```
f = StringJoin["#", IntegerString[#, 16, 2]] &

rgbs = {{72, 61, 139}, {75, 0, 130}, {0, 255, 127}}

f /@ rgbs // Column
```

> #483d8b
>
> #4b0082
>
> #00ff7f

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp, 39 characters

```
(format()"#~@{~2,'0x~}"#1=(read)#1##1#)
```

Read three integers, return a string.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6, 63 bytes

```
h=>'#'+h.split` `.map(x=>(x<16?0:'')+(x*1).toString(16)).join``
```

Comment: Coincidentally, I ended up writing almost exactly the same thing as you before I saw yours. Very nice =) They're close enough that I won't post mine, but you can save a few bytes on your mapping with this: `x=>(x<16?0:'')+x.toString(16)`

Comment: Also, no need to include the `r=` at the beginning. It still counts as a function even as an anonymous function, since you can invoke it without having to assign anything.

Comment: Whoops. Meant the map to be: `x=>(x<16?0:'')+(x*1).toString(16)` Yours and my first one there currently give wrong values for `x>9`.

Comment: This currently returns `#7261139` instead of `#483D8B` for the first test case.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (55 chars)

```
'#'+''.join([hex(int(i))[2:].upper() for i in input()])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 40 bytes

```
s='#';exec's+="%02X"%input();'*3;print s
```

Reads the input from three separate lines. Abuses `exec` and string multiplication.

Example usage:

```
$ python2 rgbint.py
72
61
139
#483D8B

$ python2 rgbint.py
75
0
130
#4B0082

$ python2 rgbint.py
0
255
127
#00FF7F
```