# Capitalize String

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string, capitalize it. By capitalization I mean `conTeNT-lENgth` changes to `Content-Length`. In the example I showed the string with 2 words with `-` as the word boundary. However I expect you to write the code for the string containing any number of words separated by a **single** character as the boundary. This boundary may change across the string.

**Conditions**

1. using `regular expressions` is **not allowed**.
2. there could be any number of words in a sentence(string).
3. each word will consist of `English` letters`[a-zA-Z]` of any case.
4. different words in the sentence will be separated by a single character. This character will **only** be any one of `-`, `.`,  , `/`, `&`, `#`. You can safely assume that sentence will **not** contain any other character except the mentioned ones.
5. word boundaries should be preserved in the output.
6. shortest code wins.

For example your program should output `Begin/With.Type&Content` for `BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt`.

```
Some test cases:
 "aGeNT ACcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe" 
 "type&AgeNt/CC/COnteNt lEnGth#acCePT/AgeNt.RAnGe-Cc/contEnt/cODe" 
 "cc/rEspoNCe.lEngtH#tYpE-witH&UsEr/bEgIN&uSer.AGEnT&begIn/aCCEPt/Cc" 
 "lENgTH#USeR.tYpE/BeGiN&LENGth tYpe/ACCEpt#rANge/codE&AnD-ACCepT/ConTenT" 
 "contENT/ACcEpT" 
 "BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt"
 "Code.cc#User.lenGTh-USer-AND&tyPE TypE&leNgtH.tYPe usER.UseR&with" 
 "RaNgE&COnTeNT WITh CoNTENT-TypE tyPe"
 "BEgin COdE#uSeR#aGeNt.USeR"
 "TypE LENGth"
```

Comment: What you call capitalization is actually a transformation to camel-case.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre No, what he's given as "test cases" are more like camel case. What's being called capitalization is closer to Title Case.

Comment: Can you please provide the expected output for the test cases? It seems some built-in functions may assume that all-caps words (like `/CC/` in line 2, or `-AND&` in line 7) should be left alone. Is this ok, for this challenge?

Comment: Does the input always begin with a word or it may start with a separator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### GolfScript, <strike>36</strike> <strike>27</strike> 19 characters

```
0\{95&+.47>32*\}%\;
```

A quite basic GolfScript approach which works for all input according to the specification. The examples can be tested [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ezBcezk1JisuNDc%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%3D&run=true).

Comment: Cool. Was curious whether my solution is at least twice as a professional one. :) But I am sure you will shorten this several times before the day ends.

Comment: @manatwork Now we have a factor of two ;-) Still unhappy with all the swaps.

Comment: I knew you will not disappoint me.

Answer (score 26):

**Python 3,22**

```
print(input().title())
```

This code will take a string as input from stdin and gives a capitalized output to stdout.

for example:

input:

```
BEGIN/wITH.tyPe&cOnTENt
```

ouput:

```
Begin/With.Type&Content
```

The following code is for multi-line inputs (if necessary)

**Python 3, 46**

```
import sys
for i in sys.stdin:print(i.title())
```

Comment: `while 1:print(input.title())` is a shorter equivalent for the last piece of code.

Comment: @RamchandraApte I'm not sure is it allowed or not. Your code will die with an [EOFError](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) as soon as its hits the [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file)

Comment: I think the general consensus for golfs is that as long as the output is correct, errors don't matter

Comment: Dang; as soon as I saw this question, I thought of this, but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: +1 I like this better than the golfscript one because it doesn't look like an obscenity.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

Code:

```
™
```

Explanation:

```
™   # Implicit input which is converted to title case.
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oSi&input=Y2MvckVzcG9OQ2UubEVuZ3RII3RZcEUtd2l0SCZVc0VyL2JFZ0lOJnVTZXIuQUdFblQmYmVnSW4vYUNDRVB0L0Nj)

Comment: That's pretty cool :-)

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (94)

```
prompt().split(l='').map(function(a){return l='A'>l?a.toUpperCase():a.toLowerCase()}).join('')
```

Comment: Why not arrow functions? Edit: I just realised that this is from 2013 

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica 62

**Data**

```
tests={"aGeNT ACcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe","type&AgeNt/CC/COnteNt lEnGth#acCePT/AgeNt.RAnGe-Cc/contEnt/cODe","cc/rEspoNCe.lEngtH#tYpEwitH&UsEr/bEgIN&uSer.AGEnT&begIn/aCCEPt/Cc","lENgTH#USeR.tYpE/BeGiN&LENGth tYpe/ACCEpt#rANge/codE&AnD-ACCepT/ConTenT","contENT/ACcEpT","BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt","Code.cc#User.lenGTh-USer-AND&tyPE TypE&leNgtH.tYPe usER.UseR&with","RaNgE&COnTeNT WITh CoNTENT-TypE tyPe","BEgin COdE#uSeR#aGeNt.USeR","TypE LENGth"}
```

---

**Code**

```
StringReplace[ToLowerCase@#,WordBoundary~~x_:>ToUpperCase@x]&
```

---

**Usage**

```
f["aGeNT ACcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe"]
```

> "Agent Accept/Length-Type User Range.Type"

```
f /@ tests
```

> {"Agent Accept/Length-Type User Range.Type",
> "Type&Agent/Cc/Content Length#Accept/Agent.Range-Cc/Content/Code",
> "Cc/Responce.Length#Type-With&User/Begin&User.Agent&Begin/Accept/Cc",
> "Length#User.Type/Begin&Length  Type/Accept#Range/Code&And-Accept/Content", "Content/Accept",
> "Begin/With.Type&Content",
> "Code.Cc#User.Length-User-And&Type Type&Length.Type User.User&With",
> "Range&Content With Content-Type Type",
> "Begin Code#User#Agent.User",
> "Type Length"}

Comment: -1 That's basically regex

Comment: Mathematica can run regex directly but I used something else.  It's similar to regex, but it is not regex.

Comment: `%%` `%%%` `%` `%%`

Answer (score 5):

**PHP : <strike>78</strike> <strike>73</strike> <strike>65</strike> 64 characters**

```php
$b=ucfirst;foreach(str_split($s)as$c)echo$b($c),!$b[0]=$c<A?u:l;
```

Input is passed in `$s`. It operates on the string as an array of characters.

It is a simple 2 state machine. It relies on lexical ordering of strings, and that the parser automatically assumes you meant to type a string in some cases.

The state is being stored in `$b` and is being represented as the name of the function that needs to be called on the next character. `ucfirst` and `lcfirst` are shorter to type and have identical behaviour to `strtolower`/`strtoupper` on single character strings. Also, since they only differ by one letter, we can use them efficiently to store the state. The original version needed to store the state explicitly in a boolean.

Since echo doesn't print anything for boolean false, I used a comma and the `!` operator to "hide" the assignment(which in this case is truthy) in the echo statement. This allowed me to save a character by removing the `{}`.

Comment: Please use code block markup instead of inline code, so scripts like [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) can insert the size below the code. By the way, in your code all 3 space characters can be removed.

Comment: Instead of `$b=ord($c)>64;` try `$b=$c>"@";`. Or even `$b=$c>=A;` – AFAIR that throws a warning, but good coding practices are not a virtue here.

Comment: @manatwork thanks, didn't think of that. I am already throwing a warning for using an unset variable anyway.

Comment: Hmm… What about not using $b just as a flag, but storing the actual function name in it? `$b=ucfirst;foreach(str_split($s)as$c){echo$b($c);$b[0]=$c>=A?l:u;}`.

Comment: @manatwork great! I was trying to think of a way to do that with the function. My tries were all bigger.

Comment: Actually there is one more character that you can remove by reversing the ternary: `$c<A?u:l`.

Answer (score 4):

## Powershell: 37 - 43

Depending on how you want to take the input...

**Prompt the user for input: 43**

```
(Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase((read-host))
```

**Take input from pipeline: 38**

```
(Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($input)
```

**Provide input as an argument when running the script: 37**

```
(Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($args)
```

---

**NOTE:** The above scripts will ignore all-caps words, leaving them as-is. If this needs to be accounted for, the input should be forced to lower-case before the Title Case conversion. This adds 10 characters to the first method, and 12 to the other two.

```
(Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase((read-host).ToLower())
(Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase("$input".ToLower())
(Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase("$args".ToLower())
```

Comment: Does not work according to the specification. Try `foo:bar`.

Comment: @Mormegil Which one? The read-host version, at least, works fine for me. I tested it against all the test cases in the question and they all returned as expected except for the special cases I posted in comment to the question.

Comment: `:` (colon) is not listed as a word separator in rule #4, therefore, AFAICS, `foo:bar` should result in `Foo:bar`, _not_ `Foo:Bar`. But that is just my (quite strict) reading of the specification.

Comment: @Mormegil Ah, but an equally strict interpretation could also be that the rule does not provide an exclusive list. That is, it says the separator "could be any one of..." as opposed to "can only be any one of...".

Comment: Fair enough. The specification _is_ quite hazy, anyway. :-)

Comment: @Mormegil Well, this is neat. Looks like the spec was tweaked to resolve that ambiguity, while at the same time not invalidating this answer.

Comment: You can replace `get-culture` with `culture`; see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/778/1308

Comment: @DankoDurbić Ah, I keep forgetting that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 83

```
n;main(c){c=getchar();putchar(c>96?n?c:(n=c-32):c&64?n?c+32:(n=c):(n=0,c));main();}
```

Takes lines on `stdin`, translates them to `stdout`. (Prefers `SIGINT` to `EOF`.)

Answer (score 4):

### Java - 209 characters

```
class C{
public static void main(String[]a){
for(String b:a){
char[]k=b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
for(int i=-1;i<k.length;i++){if(i<0||"-. /&#".indexOf(k[i])>=0)k[++i]=(char)(k[i]-32);}
System.out.println(k);}}}
```

I added newlines only for readability.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby: <s>60</s> <s>51</s> <s>50</s> 47 characters

```ruby
$_.downcase.chars{|c|$><<$/=$/<?0?c.upcase: c}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ for line in "${test[@]}"; do printf '%-75s | %s\n' "$line" "$( ruby -ne '$_.downcase.chars{|c|$><<$/=$/<?0?c.upcase: c}' <<< "$line" )"; done
aGeNT ACcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe                                    | Agent Accept/Length-Type User Range.Type
type&AgeNt/CC/COnteNt lEnGth#acCePT/AgeNt.RAnGe-Cc/contEnt/cODe             | Type&Agent/Cc/Content Length#Accept/Agent.Range-Cc/Content/Code
cc/rEspoNCe.lEngtH#tYpE-witH&UsEr/bEgIN&uSer.AGEnT&begIn/aCCEPt/Cc          | Cc/Responce.Length#Type-With&User/Begin&User.Agent&Begin/Accept/Cc
lENgTH#USeR.tYpE/BeGiN&LENGth tYpe/ACCEpt#rANge/codE&AnD-ACCepT/ConTenT     | Length#User.Type/Begin&Length Type/Accept#Range/Code&And-Accept/Content
contENT/ACcEpT                                                              | Content/Accept
BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt                                                     | Begin/With.Type&Content
Code.cc#User.lenGTh-USer-AND&tyPE TypE&leNgtH.tYPe usER.UseR&with           | Code.Cc#User.Length-User-And&Type Type&Length.Type User.User&With
RaNgE&COnTeNT WITh CoNTENT-TypE tyPe                                        | Range&Content With Content-Type Type
BEgin COdE#uSeR#aGeNt.USeR                                                  | Begin Code#User#Agent.User
TypE LENGth                                                                 | Type Length
```

Comment: Isn't `l==l.swapcase` the same as `l<?0` (not tested)? At least for the input allowed for this task.

Comment: Yes. Now that batman emphasized that no other separators have to be expected, indeed that is shorter. Thank you, @Howard.

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge 98 - <s>24</s> 45

```
~\j:'``!3*j' -;:'``b*j:'/`!3*j' +#;:,'/`!jc#@
```

Writing this hurt my brain.

This takes input through `~` and if the previous character was one of the separators (or if there was no previous character), it executes

```
:'``!3*j' -;
```

This snippet takes the character, and if its ascii value is greater than or equal to `a`, it subtracts 32 from it, thus changing it to upper case. If it is less than `a`, `3*j` skips the adjustment. Afterwards, it skips the next part. This part handles changing from upper case to lower case (I'm sure it can be merged with the next part; I'm just not sure how):

```
:'``b*j:'/`!3*j' +#;
```

The character is printed (`,`), then this checks if the character is one of the boundaries:

```
'/`!
```

It basically compares the character to the ascii value of `/`. If the character is not a boundary, the code pushes `12` so that it will skip the capitalization adjustment the next time around. `#` skips over the end program: `@`, and if the end of the input is reached, `~` sends the code execution back to the `@`, ending the program.

Answer (score 3):

#### R, <s>143</s> 116

A solution a bit long maybe but here we go:

```
f=function(x){a=sapply(1:nchar(x),function(y)substr(tolower(x),y,y));d=c(1,which(!a%in%letters)+1);a[d]=toupper(a[d]);cat(a,sep="")}
```

Slightly ungolfed and explained:

```r
f <- function(x){
    #Split the string in characters and "lower-case" everything
    a <- sapply(1:nchar(x),function(y)substr(tolower(x),y,y))
    #Select the first character and each character following a 
    #character that doesn't belong to lower case alphabet
    d <- c(1,which(!a%in%letters)+1)
    #Make those ones uppercase.
    a[d] <- toupper(a[d])
    #Output (stdout) while pasting them back together.
    cat(a,sep="")
    }
```

**Edit**: 116 characters

The main challenge here is to vectorize `substr`. Here's another less verbose way.

```
f=function(x){n=1:nchar(x);a=mapply(substr,tolower(x),n,n);d=c(T,!a%in%letters);a[d]=toupper(a[d]);cat(a[n],sep="")}
```

Indented:

```r
f <- function(x){
    n <- 1:nchar(x)
    a <- mapply(substr,tolower(x),n,n)
    d <- c(T,!a%in%letters) #This has been simplified as well
    a[d] <- toupper(a[d])
    cat(a[n],sep="") #Because a is now 1 char longer than x, need to subset a
    }
```

Usage:

```
> f("aGeNT ACcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe")
Agent Accept/Length-Type User Range.Type
```

Comment: You can save some characters. Since `a` consits of lowercase characters only, there's no need to check for matches with uppercase `LETTERS`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein indeed, thanks!

Comment: Another one: You can replace `TRUE` with `T`.

Comment: Originally i had the `tolower` later.

Comment: OK, here's another one ;-) You can replace `mapply(substr,tolower(x),n,n) `with `strsplit(tolower(x),"")[[1]]` to save one character.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Ahah yes indeed. Although one would argue that argument `split` (here an empty string) is technically treated as a regular expression! :)

Comment: Good point! Unless you specify, `fixed = FALSE`, it's based on regular expressions.

Comment: Don't care to count but maybe the following is slightly shorter: `x<-tolower(strsplit(x,"")[[1]]);
u<-which(!x%in%letters);
x[u+1]<-toupper(x[u+1]);
cat(x,sep="")`

Comment: Down to 105 bytes by using `utf8toInt` : `function(x,y=utf8ToInt(x)){s=which(y<64);y[-s]=y[-s]%%32+96;m=c(1,s+(s>0));y[m]=y[m]%%32+64;intToUtf8(y)}`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (string->string), 67 bytes

```
s=>[...s].map(a=>l=a[`to${'A'>l?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`](),l='').join``
```

Try it:

```js
f=s=>[...s].map(a=>l=a[`to${'A'>l?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`](),l='').join``

console.log(f('aGeNT aCcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe'));
console.log(f('type&AgeNt/CC/COnteNt lEnGth#acCePT/AgeNt.RAnGe-Cc/contEnt/cODe'));
console.log(f('cc/rEspoNCe.lEngtH#tYpE-witH&UsEr/bEgIN&uSer.AGEnT&begIn/aCCEPt/Cc'));
console.log(f('lENgTH#USeR.tYpE/BeGiN&LENGth tYpe/ACCEpt#rANge/codE&AnD-ACCepT/ConTenT'));
console.log(f('contENT/ACcEpT'));
console.log(f('BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt'));
console.log(f('Code.cc#User.lenGTh-USer-AND&tyPE TypE&leNgtH.tYPe usER.UseR&with'));
console.log(f('RaNgE&COnTeNT WITh CoNTENT-TypE tyPe'));
console.log(f('BEgin COdE#uSeR#aGeNt.USeR'));
console.log(f('TypE LENGth'));
```

## [Jacob](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/jacob)'s variant - JavaScript (char[]->char[]), 55 bytes

```
s=>s.map(a=>l=a[`to${'A'>l?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`](),l='')
```

Try it:

```js
f=s=>s.map(a=>l=a[`to${'A'>l?'Upp':'Low'}erCase`](),l='')

g = s => f([...s]).join``

console.log(g('aGeNT aCcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe'));
console.log(g('type&AgeNt/CC/COnteNt lEnGth#acCePT/AgeNt.RAnGe-Cc/contEnt/cODe'));
console.log(g('cc/rEspoNCe.lEngtH#tYpE-witH&UsEr/bEgIN&uSer.AGEnT&begIn/aCCEPt/Cc'));
console.log(g('lENgTH#USeR.tYpE/BeGiN&LENGth tYpe/ACCEpt#rANge/codE&AnD-ACCepT/ConTenT'));
console.log(g('contENT/ACcEpT'));
console.log(g('BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt'));
console.log(g('Code.cc#User.lenGTh-USer-AND&tyPE TypE&leNgtH.tYPe usER.UseR&with'));
console.log(g('RaNgE&COnTeNT WITh CoNTENT-TypE tyPe'));
console.log(g('BEgin COdE#uSeR#aGeNt.USeR'));
console.log(g('TypE LENGth'));
```

Comment: Nice answer! You can save a couple bytes by using character arrays instead of strings, by the way.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you! Can you please show how?

Comment: Just get rid of the `[...s]` and the `.join\`\``. It's fairly common practice on this site - see https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8964/108687. If you use this, just make sure to mention in the answer that it uses character arrays.

Comment: https://tio.run/##dVLRatswFH3fVxhcZAdm6X3DGa4inEBQjKswSilEVW4VF1c2lroQxr49vcrehvcmrs45Ovccvelf2pupG0PhhiNcX8urL5eevusx1@WyL/XTIQx3v7MqW/Y/sv04Zt@y7XDO/sDEtYfDc7742pdZtrjaEpmv@ROl1D8v6NvQucPhixmcH3qg/WBzm2e6BqkSzY0YFdsKZ9WpCI8NJPsHaJNJSyuoujSQLRbf/@WGywiksiAD45zxnQt4THrh6nBKteHQKHa7pm3laii4YagQhAvM7FazksawSfhxkBxH6Cas0/A4iuLchTXZezGxF2E3knw8wESrWjhFXsBuHNOciwZ9mDnVXkir1mlciUY5dg91J8lWSHSa4ARYhfwxpFMlLaDLoyCVWxU4BcyFD06BU7OG40IS97wlOIeIbzl23qg1DZdGEBPFZJiDcmycGpPuPW7Xg6uxDDQ9FZVckUhO1GUUpAeJwdBbTR9etBTxLcGITnOibeyQYDsqNv1zo04JH6RC00VUS8J/2r0XtnMJ3x1Fimm3afwpgcYM59A3qb@BxuvrJw

Comment: @Jacob Thank you! I read the all answers. But I think it is a big cheating to define second function which do some part of my function. The conditions say that my function must return a string and accept a string so I think it isn't fair to define another function which prepare data for main function and modifies the output

Comment: Well I would say it's fine, because the extra function is only used to make defining the test cases easier. You could still call `f` with an array of characters, it would just make the test cases harder to write. But if you feel like it's cheating then you don't need it

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `s=>s.replace(/./g,a=>l=a[\`to${'A'>l?'Upp':'Low'}erCase\`](),l='')` for 64 bytes, it still takes and returns a string

Comment: @Jacob I can't use regexp because of  "using regular expressions is **not allowed**"

Comment: I don't think `.replace(/./g,a=>)` counts as using a regex in the terms of this challenge, because it's just a shorter method of using `.split``.map(...).join`, while the usage of regex specified in the challenge description bans using regex to solve the main part of the challenge

Comment: @Jacob I added your variant :)

Answer (score 2):

### C# – 110

A simple finite-state-machine-based processing:

```cs
x.Aggregate(new{b=1>0,r=""},(s,c)=>new{b="-. /&#".Contains(c),r=s.r+(s.b?Char.ToUpper(c):Char.ToLower(c))}).r
```

(where `x` is the `string` to capitalize)

and of course, if you want to be boring (after the specification was updated), you can use

```cs
new CultureInfo(9).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(x)
```

or, with all the boring boilerplate:

```cs
class C{static void Main(string[]a){System.Console.WriteLine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(9).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(a[0]));}}
```

Comment: Nah, won't compile as C# is no scripting language and you need to encapsulate this in a class.

Comment: Says who?
`Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.2.20906.1
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
> "foobar".Aggregate(new{b=1>0,r=""},(s,c)=>new{b="-. /&#".Contains(c),r=s.r+(s.b?Char.ToUpper(c):Char.ToLower(c))}).r
"Foobar"`
But if you really care about the boring boilerplate, add 112 characters of it.

Comment: You can cut the `public` and `string[]a` from the boilerplate

Comment: Oh yeah, you’re right with `public`, but I need the arguments, as that is what I process…

Answer (score 2):

### Forth, 135

```
: s swap ;
: c 1 begin key dup 96 > if s if 32 - then 0 s 
else dup 64 > if s 0= if 32 + then 0 s then else 1 s then then emit again ; c
```

Translated output is written to `stdout` as it reads from `stdin`.

Comment: "then then emit again" rhyming with forth!

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript 102

```
prompt().split(o=q='').map(function(c){o+=(q)?c.toLowerCase():c.toUpperCase(),q=('A'>c)?0:1})
alert(o)
```

Comment: You need no `(`…`)` around the ternary condition. Even more, you not need the second ternary: `function(c){o+=q?c.toLowerCase():c.toUpperCase(),q='@'<c}`.

Answer (score 2):

### Befunge-98 (29), C (65)

Since the method/algorithm is pretty much the same, I include both versions in the same post.  Both rely on keeping track of whether the last character was a symbol or letter, in order to know whether to lowercase a letter or not.

**Befunge-98 (29)**

```
#@~:'0` #v_,0>
',++@'% '<   ^
```

**C (65)**

```c
c,d;main(){for(;~(c=getchar());d=c>48)putchar(c<48?c:c&95|32*d);}
```

Answer (score 2):

### [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <del>113</del> <del>103</del> 98 bytes

```
{OFS=""
for(n=split($0,a,"");i<=n;s=a[++i]){$i=(L?tolower(s):toupper(s))
L=!(index("-. /&#",s))}}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZFRa9swFIXf9StUuwiHxlL7us4MV9GcQFCMozDK2IOr3DlmRja2QhZKf3t65b6Jq3N1zndUX/7dbu@7n/ssisjffkxcNg1d65P7x2W9jKLFc/s9c89TVv9@eGj/LN7v2yzZ/vB9119gTKbFN9@fh2E@Lsg2u0tad4T/SZRyKlgcLXH88fF0u9UFaENzadVgxFa5xpxS/1oCPeyhomOtG8XNtQTirwOwvAHthZRC7pzHI@2UK/wprq2E0oj5mle5KyCVVtjeeeW8sLsVEGvFqKah1xI4bjV@HfvXQaWX1q/ZYVKjeFPNRrPzHkaeF8oZ9gbNxolaSlWiqSWd0o1ZxyEZD7viBYpWs63SmIHiBESO4sHHY64bQP@jYrlbpTgFxJO9M@AMmXNpjDtTk/CKE5eNWXN/LRWzQaY9kf0RuLXxYcJEHbgCq0HvMc31igUlNddBsQ40wvC5tPOkKo76iiHWiVShPoZdmVDyr405Udlrg95pWKU@FPuimtZRuTuqGNmrOPyI5wGSzKIvvE8)

This works fine for single line content, but for multi-line input a few more inits need to be added

### [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 104 bytes

```
{OFS=i=s=L=""
for(n=split($0,a,"");i<=n;s=a[++i]){$i=(L?tolower(s):toupper(s))
L=!(index("-. /&#",s))}}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JZFRa9swFIXf9Ss0uwiHxtL2us4MV9GcgFGMozDK2IOr3DlmRja2QhZKf3t65b2Jq3N1znfUXP/e72/7H4esy@aszKKI/BmmxGXz2Hc@efi8btZRtHrqvmXuac6aX4@P3e/V20OXJeV3P/TDFaZkXn31w2Ucl@OKlNmnpHMn@JdEKaeCxdEax@/vX@73pgBtaC6tGo0olWvNOfUvFdDjAWo6NbpV3NwqIP42Astb0F5IKeTeeTzSXrnCn@PGSqiMWK55nbsCUmmFHZxXzgu73wCxVkxqHgctgeNW67exfxlVeu38lh1nNYlX1e40uxxg4nmhnGGv0O6caKRUFZpa0ivdmm0ckvGwK56h6DQrlcYMFCcgchSPPp5y3QL6nxTL3SbFKSCeHJwBZ8iSS2PchZqEV5y47syW@1ulmA0y7YkcTsCtjY8zJurBFVgNek9prjcsKKm5jYr1oBGGL6VdZlVz1NcMsc6kDvUx7MqEkn/uzJnKQRv0TsMq9aHYZ9V2jsr9ScXIXsfhRzwPkGQR/cf7AA)

It would have been nice to take advantage of AWK's automatic splitting of a record into fields and modifying said fields, but that throws away the field separators. :(

This update throws away the idea of tacking characters onto a string and then printing the string. Instead, each character becomes its own field. Without the `OFS=""` bit, each character/field would be separated by a space when printed, which isn't what was requested.

Realizing that "" is essentially the same thing as 0 in AWK shortens the byte-count for the multi-line version a little bit. (I know it's different... I said 'essentially' :p )

Comment: Are you sure? None of the codes seems to produce the required output neither with `gawk`, `mawk` or `original-awk`. (Tested on Ubuntu.)

Comment: It was written using `gawk` on an RHEL6 box, but then transcribed to a windows box.  There could very well be a transcription issue.  I'll try testing after work when I  can do testing and posting on the same machine.... I think I see the issue, anyway.  `l=0` should be `L=0`

Comment: Hopefully it works now, @manatwork . Thanks for the testing. :)

Comment: Now seems to work correctly. Not checked all test cases, but seems to be possible to reduce it a bit: `{for(l=split($0,a,$0="");i<=l;s=a[++i]){$0=$0(L?toupper(s):tolower(s));L=index("-. /&#",s)}}1`.

Comment: I like your use of changing `$0` and the `1` label to avoid the `print` command are things I haven't thought of doing.  I'll have to keep it in mind for future golfing :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 122 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(chr(ord(c)+[[0,0],[0,32],[-32,0]][('@'<c<'[')-('`'<c<'{')]['@'<p<'['or'`'<p<'{'])for c,p in zip(s,'-'+s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFRa9swGHzfrxA1yDaNpdK8jQ7mKsIJFMW4CqN4gTmyYntkspBVSrofn33KoOC@2NLpu@O@O3v2/WiWl@O3n5dT8@fQNmj6Gsfk9ziYRPUuGV2bqPS2ru8Wd/sFfJf38MuW93Dd10n8PX5QD3Edp1kS/7qe/8bpvg64DfjoAmwDvE@Po0NqYdFg0Ptgk2kRZ/HtlKYX6wbjk2Ny0xRaSJQzxa2kT9x0ss/8S6nR7llXyDWi40SeS32Tpl8@SP5sNc47LTxljLKt8XBEJ24K30eNYrqU9PpMqtwUOmOKqtF4bjxV29VcSynq@GRHwTQBhc6vI/9iefY2@DXeTdzRA@82Ar8@a0fyghuJD7rbGNowxkswoGZyJy46uY6CexJ06KMuBoGfuABvCBBNcyBaH7lcdBp8tRznZpUBqiECNhqpjZxbDN4FrHRNafYU1A1928g18eeSYxXows9m2NhqolS0m2CDkzYFRAz@XJaLFQ4sJM@W45MWsDy5hv868YrAfIUhhn6mVoVKMGQuQ3E/NrJHbBQS/GVBBvnPZT3yDupn25ZHkGEVhcY9CQHNxq7k/zEBfvkH)

Not a great score, but I wanted to try it without builtin string operations for case changing.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 13 characters

In the Immediate window

```vb
?[Proper(A1)]
```

Function takes input from cell `A1`

### VBScript

```vb
Set xlapp = CreateObject("excel.application")
wscript.echo xlapp.Evaluate("Proper(""BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt"")"
```

Comment: Could you provide some help on usage? I get “Compile error: External name not defined”. (In Word 2013 on the Developer tab I clicked Visual Basic, then in Visual Basic for Application I copy-pasted your code in the Immediate window and pressed Enter.)

Comment: @manatwork I should have clarified it was in Excel. You can do this from Word but the path is longer as you need to automate Excel.

Comment: Cool. Works perfectly when VBA is started from Excel 2013.

Comment: Works in directly in Excel as well: `=PROPER(A1)`, also 11 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, 74 bytes

```
1c$=LCASE$(INPUT$(1))
IF f=0THEN c$=UCASE$(c$)
f=c$>"@
?c$;
IF""<c$GOTO 1
```

Bytes are counted in [CP-437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437);  is a single byte (character code 20).

The input method here is a bit strange: characters are typed one at a time, and their capitalization is converted before they are displayed. So when you type in `aGeNT`, it appears on screen as `Agent`. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> ends the program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 9 bytes

```python
str.title
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v7ikSK8ksyQn9f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pF`, 42 bytes

```perl
$\.=~$=?uc:lc,$==index'?/.- &#',$_ for@F}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lRs@2TsXWvjTZKidZR8XWNjMvJbVC3V5fT1dBTVldRyVeIS2/yMGttvr//0T3VL8QBUfnZNeCEH0f17z0kAzdksiAVIXQ4NQghaJEv3RXvZDKgNR/@QUlmfl5xf91C9wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>20</s> 15 bytes

```
f:ʀĠ•ƛḣv⇩$⇧p;f∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJmOsqAxKDigKLGm+G4o3bih6kk4oencDtm4oiRIiwiIiwiWW91cmUgYS1uRXJkIl0=)

Or, if that's too long:

### 1 byte

```
ǐ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLHkCIsIiIsIllvdXJlIGEtbkVyZCJd)

### Explained

```
f:ʀĠ•ƛḣv⇩$⇧p;f∑
f:               # Push two copies of the letters of the input
  ʀ              # is each letter in the first copy in the alphabet?
   Ġ             # group that on consecutive elements - this has the effect of grouping words.
    •            # reshape the other copy of the letters to have the same shape as that
     ƛ           # to each sublist L:
      ḣv⇩        #     push L[0] and [lower(x) for x in L[1:]] - on single length strings this just leaves L[0] on the stack.
         $⇧p     #     uppercase L[0] and prepend it to the other list
            ;    # close map
             f∑  # deep flatten and summate to get a single string - the `d` flag would save 3 bytes here by removing this pair and allowing structure autocompletion to save a byte.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 153 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(s string)(o string){c:=0<1
for i:=range s{x:=s[i:i+1]
if c{o+=ToUpper(x);c=!c}else{o+=ToLower(x)}
c=Contains("-. /&#",x)}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZJBitswFIahS59CtcE4TC11diVtFq4inMCgGI9CGUoXHkVWTB3JyAqZELLtHUo3odBD9CjtaSo5nUUns-jK4n9Pv7_3P337LvXpZ1fxz5UUYFM1Kmg2nTYWhvXGhj-2tk7f_Pr6qPXWNEr2YVBvFQd10oOzMkr04-nAx5PX766DWhvQjCemUs64PzyMJ_3HZtxcXX8Kmhrwg76aML3sOmGSh9FbPnnJj6LtxVm_0btBPwZ8grWyjqtPwhQCFEfhK68bYbdGHc-Av198GYA8fzICh6BwKLZVSZ2A8L3IG4V2czaDdl-QmGvFBLUhGI3-6atyQRnIMCcdQzdESbZO7V0hwPJWlMBUVBLI9oUIwdObdt-JOJPOFGGM8EJZdwQtUbldRxXHomBoKMMyU7lIMUcOwhJlEV9MnzHkHBnSd5piAZ2NtLPI3nUk3TV2Fi97YtA9kXMab2-FgVlOFIvvhZwrVGFMCkfBLz1bQiWbRX4Y6M2Qz4XGN4Q6SuAUgTJ3u7ORyagUjnBF4kxNU6cKlwj2sSn2DKwfhboJh-Qu6_-bP9YrATmPlr0bqhUqd_k7WpNmdBr7m4DtOxK3gro84LCZbU9K6PrL2CWzvvx16ZcWu4Uwv9oPc7YGWFPmaFPvBeywzqe8RDYK4MWKRC7fMvLvwkKf20XrYHJOcKj9fY6n0_n7Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 9 bytes

```julia
titlecase
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHRitswEHy/rxAxiDuoJfoDB66yOIFDMT6Fchx98CmL7OIqxt5wDfTf010H@tg3MTujnZn9eRmH7uvv240GGjF2C95@ddPjUD7/Ax6Hpy/vD2oTzzmgD@UIPlG/YeQb1kO2n/uwM3RtQN8ZJKOuZqqqXIQp2BfIKfQlvTWojq/YqrnzCUy4NrhRTKbrhLpKLLXOWXfIxE81Qq6pL7rosAl2HZu2yjWWLlpeRZDJxsP2/keMdoZlOnuHhpWJdgW9TVB@DrTTxwVm@wFp7/XlFWdT1ZCD/sC0z7ZzDhpeHNdvJFzYFeLSiN5KRq9fwLMXxQjaigUTFXPlE7KPE@gqb0tGkaM6qSCHuyXx6Nn62sIK/acxdz6hibE4LmxwxFxzY2xjLiu/1UJW4TqBHpHbZ7V0eVmgNcxvNafs1wWtNKu5QjmV@r4PvXJnH9hGKXJF0rkYgTRk5Q4nKLiRtpB7kZHYMl2p98ybhx9Pyvx5VtM8ZBrz7S8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.65 bytes

```
zV
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLqsIgDCh_wXanVPfMPP1yzxAPvZLKAFe15Py8kFS_Eog0AA)

Just a built-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Node.js), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

Exact same score as [the RegEx approach](https://tio.run/##NZHhauswDIV/3z1FaMC0sNhP0EHmirRQ3JC5XMY2WOpqbkZmm8S7XZ@@V07ZPyMdSd85/mz/taMZuhAL5494/Vhex@XDyKPf@jMOsh1xvuADhr41OBevBy7s/c/y4YcU@xB@FYur8W70PfLe2/nL3Z9ZW6HSWSkNBC224Kw@FfG5xmz/hE02tMoC15caZ/ckjpeArLSoopBSyJ2L9Mx6cFU85a2RWGsxtXlTugoLaQTdi@CiMLvVbYcxYoAxeCUJgu7FdR6fAxTnLq7ZfoRBHMBuFPt@woGXFTjNDmg3TrRSQk2HzbSmB2X1Ok@UPM2LR6w6xbagiCWjCoqSBkLMh1JZJI4jsNKtCqoiWZXeaXT6hpQYFaFPKUyltM2J80avebzUwEySqzj1JH0ANybfj0TYo6soMuIYilKtWFJn@hKA9ajIHJ/C/B6h4aRvGNk8TVuaFC2jDHX6gL8bfcqkV5o4ijSexd/QH8F2LpO7I@SUSZOnH4s8GZ/ak/hme3b3xr/aMP9Y8E/fufdX9764/gc) would have been!

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s.toLowerCase()).map(x=c=>x=x>64?c:c^32)+``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZHditswEIWvu09hYhAxXUuwLb0oOIujCCcQFONVKEt/iFeZOF68krGVJnn6dKTQOzE6M/OdM@/133rUQ9u71Ng93A7Zbcxm89PhAMN0pM6u7RkGXo8wTRL6UffTS6az2SW7zL59fdbf9Z8vT8nn3e6mrRltB7SzzfTnw6dJXYBUUc616BVbC9OoY@peS4i2L1BFQy0bQdW1hMkjit21B5I3IB3jnPGNcfiMOmEKd4xrzaFULHzTKjcFpFwz3OeEcUxvFvcZWrNBjL2VHCFwn1vG7rUX6bl1S7IdxcDeRLOS5PQCA80LYRR5g2ZlWM25KHGxDmM6IRu1jD0l9f1sDkUryVpIZImwAizHht7FQy4bQI69ILlZpFgFtMqtUWDUHckzSkQPKYSSn2bYeaWW1F1LQbSXSxf@OB6Aah1vRyTswBQYGXIMaS4XxKsjde0F6UCiORrCPI2ioqivCNo8himVj5Zghsof4MdKHSNupUKO1LdH7n/oc9G0JuKbvYgxkyr2F3PUGw/fQXy3PXn4HU5/SOi7bc3ul9klt38) (includes all test cases)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 36 bytes

```
{,/{`c$x-32*~!#x}'_(&1,~~"a{"'_x)_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#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)

- `_(&1,~~"a{"'_x)_x` split input after each non-letter and lowecase it, e.g. `"Begin/With.Type&Content"` to `("begin/";"with.";"type&";"content")`
- `` {`c$x-32*~!#x}' `` subtract 32 from the first character in each word and 0 from the rest (in effect capitalizing the first letter and leaving the others unchanged)
- `,/` flatten back into a single string and (implicitly) return

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL, 179

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(MAX)='foo',@X VARCHAR(2),@ INT=0WHILE @<LEN(@T)SELECT @X=SUBSTRING(@T,@,2),@+=1,@T=STUFF(@T,@,1,IIF(@X LIKE'[a-Z]_',LOWER(RIGHT(@X,1)),UPPER(RIGHT(@X,1))))PRINT @T
```

Try the SELECT version in SQL Server 2012 [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21970).

Replace "foo" with the input string.  The char count is for a zero-length string.  This code traverses the string using an index, uppercasing or lowercasing the character at that position based on the previous character.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

```javascript
c=>a=>c.split``.map(b=>a="A">a?b.toUpperCase():b.toLowerCase()).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYuxCsIwFAD/pYNNBp@7kIiKqCDiUPe8xteSEvNCEyx@fWwHx7vjBvxgsqOLeR34RaVTxSqNSltI0btsDLwxinZx1b7SuGsh8zNGGo@YSMjtwjee/ixhYBeMKZZDYk/guRedqA90dmEzXZsL5O/jtJpzQ/dcy3kpPw)

I am sure this can be golfed further.

## Note :

Takes input via `f(string)()` , the last are required but perform nothing.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, <s>77</s> 75 bytes

This solution fully meets the task rules (even ambiguous example `foo:bar`).

```powershell
-join($args|% t*y|%{"$_"|%('ToU*r','ToL*r')[+$l];$l=!('# -./&'|% Co*s $_)})
```

*See also [the Powershell solution with builtin function ToTitleCase](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15987/80745) from @Iszi.*

Explained test script:

```powershell
$f = {

-join(
$args|% t*y|%{                   # for each char from input string
    "$_"|%('ToU*r','ToL*r')[+$l] # evaluate ToUpper or ToLower method depend on $l (lower) value
                                 # Note the variable $l is not defined for a first char
                                 # so it evaluates toUpper for the first char 
    $l=!('# -./&'|% Co*s $_)     # golfed form for $l=!'# -./&'.Contains($_) expression
                                 # =0 if the current char is specified separator (toUpper for next char)
}                                # =1 otherwise (toLower for next char)
)                                # finally, join all chars to a result string

}

@(
    ,('foo:bar'                                                                 ,'Foo:bar')
    ,('aGeNT ACcEpT/LEngTh-tYPe USeR raNgE.TyPe'                                ,'Agent Accept/Length-Type User Range.Type')
    ,('type&AgeNt/CC/COnteNt lEnGth#acCePT/AgeNt.RAnGe-Cc/contEnt/cODe'         ,'Type&Agent/Cc/Content Length#Accept/Agent.Range-Cc/Content/Code')
    ,('cc/rEspoNCe.lEngtH#tYpE-witH&UsEr/bEgIN&uSer.AGEnT&begIn/aCCEPt/Cc'      ,'Cc/Responce.Length#Type-With&User/Begin&User.Agent&Begin/Accept/Cc')
    ,('lENgTH#USeR.tYpE/BeGiN&LENGth tYpe/ACCEpt#rANge/codE&AnD-ACCepT/ConTenT' ,'Length#User.Type/Begin&Length Type/Accept#Range/Code&And-Accept/Content')
    ,('contENT/ACcEpT'                                                          ,'Content/Accept')
    ,('BeGin/wITH.tyPE&conTeNt'                                                 ,'Begin/With.Type&Content')
    ,('Code.cc#User.lenGTh-USer-AND&tyPE TypE&leNgtH.tYPe usER.UseR&with'       ,'Code.Cc#User.Length-User-And&Type Type&Length.Type User.User&With')
    ,('RaNgE&COnTeNT WITh CoNTENT-TypE tyPe'                                    ,'Range&Content With Content-Type Type')
    ,('BEgin COdE#uSeR#aGeNt.USeR'                                              ,'Begin Code#User#Agent.User')
    ,('TypE LENGth'                                                             ,'Type Length')
) | % {
    $s,$e = $_
    $r = &$f $s
    "$($r-ceq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: Foo:bar
True: Agent Accept/Length-Type User Range.Type
True: Type&Agent/Cc/Content Length#Accept/Agent.Range-Cc/Content/Code
True: Cc/Responce.Length#Type-With&User/Begin&User.Agent&Begin/Accept/Cc
True: Length#User.Type/Begin&Length Type/Accept#Range/Code&And-Accept/Content
True: Content/Accept
True: Begin/With.Type&Content
True: Code.Cc#User.Length-User-And&Type Type&Length.Type User.User&With
True: Range&Content With Content-Type Type
True: Begin Code#User#Agent.User
True: Type Length
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 10 bytes

```sh
<<<${(C)1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JVBNi8IwEL3vrwjtEvTQhL17ycahLUgsGg8eaxxTQWJpZ5Gu@Nu7iXsb3sz7mt@xmy@L5XNerVafz4Vefr3m18eFZd9YXoN81LYSNDXA3T1YNJSlXVuisUxpB72VGwjedgUdG2SHPe7Y0BoPwk4Nvo9p6pErH7lSa6m3geLIbhBK6vLWaWysfK/FToUSC@1k9CIIJN12jRlLIs7JAcb@bjSKSPVU5XTsoXhcqeKHEQZ5Al8b/rPHQagSguUn9HWQrdbQRGf3r3MD422Vp5wiCchU0/ANmJiGRQSlioye8kEZjzHJGbgK6yKiGMvq9IVgMzb/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 28 bytes

Use of a [dedicated function around since v4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) makes a shorter and easier answer than [elder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16672/104387)

```php
echo ucwords(strtolower($s));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.6, <s>52</s> 51 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
let f=\.capitalized as(String)->_
```

[Try it on SwiftFiddle!](https://swiftfiddle.com/jbucoa5elffxpjg4kn5kqhwilu) For some reason, this has to be typed using `as`; `let f:(String)->_=\.capitalized` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 47 bytes

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(x=c=>x=x>64?c|32&c/2:c&~32)+``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZJha9swEIY/r7/CxCASNkuQjn0oOMNRDidQlOAqjLIN4ioXx8WTja2sCZT99eyk0G/m7r27533l1/JvOZi@7lxi2z1eD@l1SGfz0@GA/XiY8D9lNz6nJp2d0/Ps29fv5v1@yoyYPhj27346@bzbXU1rh7ZB3rTV@Ofdp1GZo9JRJg10WjyCrfQxcc8bjLZPWER9qSrg@rLB0RcSu0uHLKtQOSGlkGvr6DNqwObuGJdG4kaL0OZFZnNMpBF0z4F1wqwXtx3GiB6GrlWSIOieW8buuYPkrXZLth2gFy9QrRQ7PWHPsxysZi9YrawopYQNHTZhTQOq0svYU3I/L@aY14o9giKWiCooMhroXNxnqkLi2APL7CKhKpJV2VqNVt@QPKMi9JBCKPltVryt9JK7ywaY8XLlQk9S9NyYeDsQYYM2p8iIo08ytWBeHelLB6xBReZ4CPM0QMFJXzCyeQxbCh8towy1f4AfK32MZKs0cSR@PHIfoc@hqm0k13uIKZMi9i/muDce2kF8sz26@x1@gcOEv7a13f2yu8n1Pw)

From Shaggy's

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU5RiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWNvblRlTlQtbEVOZ3RoJmZsYWdzPQ==)

lol

Same as the Python answer - Thunno 2 is written in Python and [that's exactly what the interpreter is doing behind the scenes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/src/thunno2/commands.py#L1001C56-L1001C56).

(Built-in for title case)

Answer (score -1):

## Javascript 72 bytes

```
prompt().toLowerCase().split``.map((p,e)=>0==e?p.toUpperCase():p).join``
```

Comment: You capitalize only first letter