# Minimal code CPU stress-tester…

Tags: code-golf

### Introduction

There are lots of utilities out there capable of creating a high CPU load to stress-test your processor(s). On Microsoft Windows, you can even use the on-board `calculator.exe`, enter a large number like `999999999`, and press `n!` several times to make your CPU(s) work overtime.

But what’s in a solution if you didn’t create it yourself?

### The mission

Your mission – if you choose to accept it – is to create the smallest CPU stress-test tool on the planet.

#### Must…

1. **must** produce 100% CPU load until aborted
2. **must** take a numeric input, representing the number seconds the stress-test should run
3. **must** allow user interaction (keypress, closing terminal window, or something like that) which should enable a user to abort the stress-test and/or quit the program
4. **must** target Microsoft Windows, Mac OSx, and/or Linux.
   <sup>(Even a hamster could stress a Comodore64… therefore, you ***must*** target a current operating system.)</sup>

#### Must not…

1. **must not** use 3rd-party programs or tools which replace expected functionality.
   <sup>(Proposing shortcuts in the likes of `system('cpuStressThing.exe')` disqualifies your proposal.)</sup>

#### May…

1. **may** use any approach/algorithm/functionality to produce expected 100% CPU load
2. **may** use any programming or scripting language
   <sup>(as long as it allows practical verification of its functionality by running it)</sup>

### Winning Condition

Present the smallest sourcecode possible. The winner is the one presenting the most minimal (in size) sourcecode that complies to the above “must” and “must not” conditions. Now, make that baby burn…

---

***EDIT***

Since the question came up in the comment area… you only need to target 1 CPU core. I'm definitely not expecting you to produce a multi-core solution. After all, this should be fun – not work.

Comment: Is "100% of one core" enough, or do you mean "100% of a multi-core CPU"?

Comment: @Tobia Yep, 1 core is enough. I've edited my question to specifically include that information. Thanks for pointing me to the fact that that wasn't all too clear.

Comment: do cryptocurrency miners count/

Comment: @TheDoctor If you can make it fit the conditions I described… be my guest. It would surely be interesting to see a cryptocurrency miner that is able to beat (for example) [a 36 byte bash script](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21204/8765) in filesize.

Comment: The problem is that most miners are several thousand lines of code.

Comment: @TheDoctor **[I know](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/6961/e-sushi)** – that's why I said it would surely be interesting to see you pull it off. ;)

Comment: Given the popularity of `yes`, it would be nice to clarify whether the program is allowed to produce output.

Comment: @NateEldredge Just like it says: `may use any approach/algorithm/functionality to produce expected 100% CPU load` – so if you decide that producing output will do the job of producing a high CPU load, you are free to do that…

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Bash and standard utilities, <strike>36</strike> <strike>31</strike> <strike>22</strike> <strike>29</strike> <strike>28</strike> 26 bytes

```bash
yes :|sh&sleep $1;kill $!
```

Comment: That looks pretty gorgeous for a Bash code! That's really a nice answer!

Comment: You don't need the `:` in `do :; done`. I've found `do;done` does the job - that'll pull you in 2 bytes. Also +1 for being nearly half the length of my bash solution (I made it overly complicated for no good reason as I forgot about `$!`).

Comment: @ChrisJ - that doesn't work for me: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`;'`.  I've tried these bash versions: `3.00.15(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`, `3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`, `4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Ah - my mistake, sorry. ksh allows that syntax, bash/sh doesn't (having jsut tested).

Comment: @ChrisJ - I guess you have yourself a 34-byte `ksh` answer then ;-)

Comment: I'd put `$1` in place of `10` there, just to make it into a script that "takes numeric input".

Comment: @Tobia - fixed.

Comment: Also `/d*/n*` works just as well on my Linux box, as there's only one file with that pattern—/dev/null

Comment: @Tobia - I have `/dev/net /dev/network_latency /dev/network_throughput /dev/null`.  I guess `/d*/nu*` would do it.  <strike>Not sure if its worth introducing fragility for the sake of 2 bytes.</strike>  Of course it is - its code-golf!

Comment: I like that you suppress the output of `yes`.  I thought of a shorter way: `yes :|sh&`

Comment: @NateEldredge - very good - thanks!

Comment: @e-sushi - yes I guess there is some inefficiency of utilization when writing all those chars to the terminal window.  I've removed that part of the answer.

Comment: +1 for emoticon... `:|`

Answer (score 20):

## Bash/iputils (Linux), 14 bytes

```bash
ping6 -fw$1 ::
```

Flood-pings the IPv6 null address, until the -w deadline timer expires

<strike>*caveat - only consumes 55-60% CPU on my test VM*</strike>

Edit: - I retract my caveat.  While `top` reports the `ping6` process only consumes 55-60% CPU, I see the total CPU idle percentage (2 core VM) approach zero.  This presumably is because a good deal of the processing is going on in the kernel as it handles the packets.

Note - must be run as root.  As @Tobia comments, this seems like a reasonable requirement for something that will hog the CPU.  And the OP approved it in the comments.

Comment: +1. I would remove `sudo ` and just state that the test must be run as root. It seems like a reasonable requirement for something that will hog the CPU.

Comment: @Tobia - thanks - I think you're onto something ;-)

Comment: `ping -6 :: -t` --> only if this on windows made my cpu go wild... It's just the linux equivalent on windows, which only gives errors and doesn't even load the cpu at 1%! I'm using windows 8 pro x64 on a core2quad 2.63GHz.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - yep - I don't have windows to hand to test this.  Thats why I stated "Linux" in the title ;-)

Comment: I know, I'm just "giving" away this answer as a non-working one, for those who are thinking about trying the same in windows, as I did and failed.

Answer (score 9):

## Elf32 standalone binary - 86 bytes

I bet this is the **smallest correctly formed Elf format binary** that can be made to perform this function.  This will execute without any additional support on any linux based platform, or potentially even **without an operating system**.

Binary download: http://ge.tt/3m6h2cK1/v/0?c

Hex dump:

```hex
0000000: 7f45 4c46 0101 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000  .ELF............
0000010: 0200 0300 0100 0000 5480 0408 3400 0000  ........T...4...
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 3400 2000 0100 0000  ........4. .....
0000030: 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 0080 0408  ................
0000040: 0080 0408 5600 0000 5600 0000 0500 0000  ....V...V.......
0000050: 0010 0000 75fe                           ....u.
```

This is done by building an asm file with a minimal Elf header of its own, and skipping the use of `ld` altogether.

Assembly:

```asm
BITS 32

              org     0x08048000

ehdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Ehdr
              db      0x7F, "ELF", 1, 1, 1, 0         ;   e_ident
times 8       db      0
              dw      2                               ;   e_type
              dw      3                               ;   e_machine
              dd      1                               ;   e_version
              dd      _start                          ;   e_entry
              dd      phdr - $$                       ;   e_phoff
              dd      0                               ;   e_shoff
              dd      0                               ;   e_flags
              dw      ehdrsize                        ;   e_ehsize
              dw      phdrsize                        ;   e_phentsize
              dw      1                               ;   e_phnum
              dw      0                               ;   e_shentsize
              dw      0                               ;   e_shnum
              dw      0                               ;   e_shstrndx

ehdrsize      equ     $ - ehdr

phdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Phdr
              dd      1                               ;   p_type
              dd      0                               ;   p_offset
              dd      $$                              ;   p_vaddr
              dd      $$                              ;   p_paddr
              dd      filesize                        ;   p_filesz
              dd      filesize                        ;   p_memsz
              dd      5                               ;   p_flags
              dd      0x1000                          ;   p_align

phdrsize      equ     $ - phdr

section .text
global  _start
_start:       jnz     _start

filesize      equ     $ - $$
```

Built with `nasm -f bin tiny_cpu_stresser_elf32.asm -o tiny_cpu_stresser_elf32`

Answer (score 7):

## bash builtins only 20 bytes

```bash
ulimit -t $1;exec $0
```

Comment: @e-sushi try with a faster terminal, e.g. a text console or xterm or rxvt

Answer (score 6):

### C, 52

```c
t;main(s){for(scanf("%d",&s),t=time();time()-t<s;);}
```

Press Ctrl+C to exit.

[image]

Comment: If you do that in php, you will win! Just remove the `$i=<>` part and add `<?` to the beginning and you are good to go!

Answer (score 5):

### Perl, 32

```perl
for($i=<>,$t=time;time-$t<$i;){}
```

Now the embarrassing part: I foolishly put `$t=time` in front of `$i=<>` and was furiously trying to figure out why it exits a few seconds early.

Again, Ctrl+C to exit.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

### Unix C, 47

```c
main(int a,char**b){alarm(atoi(b[1]));for(;;);}
```

Pass the time on the command line.  Interrupt key (Ctrl-C) aborts.

Comment: if you use @ace's `scanf` trick, you can get this down to 39: `main(a){for(scanf("%d",&a),alarm(a);;);}`

Answer (score 4):

## PHP <del>43</del> 40 bytes:

I hope this is an acceptable answer:

<del>set_time_limit($_REQUEST['t']);while(!0);</del>

```php
<?for(set_time_limit($_REQUEST['t']);;);
```

I could do like this: `<?for(set_time_limit($_POST['t']);;);` but it would lose flexibility and 3 bytes.

---

And i could cheat and do like this: `<?for(set_time_limit($_REQUEST[t]);;);`. It shaves off 2 bytes, but it's not a "standard" solution. Lets keep the game fair.

---

As @fireeyedboy and @primo suggested, you can also use this solution (34 bytes):

```php
<?for(set_time_limit($argv[1]);;);
```

This allows it's use from the console, calling it like this:

```
php <filename> <time in seconds>
```

As i told, I'm not targeting the console solution, but they have to get the credit for this one.

Another answer could be this "monster", which is just both answers combined:

```php
<?for(set_time_limit($argv[1]|$_REQUEST['t']);;);
```

---

It's impossible to get key presses in php, without being on console, which I'm not targeting!

To stop it, you MUST abort the process (stopping the page from loading might stop the code)!

As a plus, it works in Android too! If you install a php server (free on Google Play).

To make it work, simply do like this:

You create a .php webpage and append `?t=<time in seconds>` to the end of the url or submit a post (using a form or even ajax).

Comment: @e-sushi I fixed the answer and reduced 3 bytes. Not as small as the Bash solution, but close. And with flexibility!

Comment: Run from the command line: replace `$_REQUEST['t']` with `$argv[1]` then call it with: `php -f cpustresstest.php <timelimit>` and abort with `^C`.

Comment: Why not use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`? 4 bytes and you are using `GET` anyway

Comment: @KristofferSHansen Because the flexibility of my code will be severely hurt.

Comment: @fireeyedboy That sounds like a good idea, but as I said, I'm not targeting to the console.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you could also use `$argv[1]`, and accept the input as a command line argument, for example: `php stress.php 4`.

Comment: @fireeyedboy and @primo, I added a new answer using the solutions you suggested. And @fireeyedboy, you don't need the `-f` argument. If you want, you can try like this: `php -r 'for(set_time_limit($argv[1]);;);' <time in seconds>`

Answer (score 4):

## Smalltalk (Smalltalk/X), 34

input: n; interrupt with CTRL-c or CMD-.

```
[[]loop]valueWithTimeout:n seconds
```

can golf better, if measured in days ;-) (just kidding):

```
[[]loop]valueWithTimeout:n days
```

[image]

or from a command line:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not a serious attempt at it, but...

## Bash, 12 bytes

```bash
:(){ :|:&};:
```

As found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

**WARNING: harmful code, don't run it on your computer!**

---

Technically:
- It produces 100% CPU load until system crashes;
- Allows user interaction to stop it (if you manage to kill all the forks, you can actually stop it...);
- You could give it a numeric input that represents the number of seconds it should run, but it won't use it.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl - 14 bytes

```perl
alarm<>;{redo}
```

Sets a `SIGALRM` to be sent in `input` seconds, which terminates the script. In the meantime, it spins in a busy-wait.

Sample usage:

```perl
$ echo 4 | perl stress.pl
Terminating on signal SIGALRM(14)
```

---

### Perl - 12 (+1) bytes

If command line options are counted as one byte each, this could be reduced to **13 bytes** using a `-n`:

```perl
alarm;{redo}
```

Sample usage:

```perl
$ echo 4 | perl -n stress.pl
Terminating on signal SIGALRM(14)
```

Comment: +1 for clever use of signals to concisely satisfy the exit requirement.

Answer (score 4):

## BrainFuck/[Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 3

```
+[]
```

It will use 100% cpu on one core until aborted. All Brainfuck programs are valid  EBF programs.

## [Zozotez LISP](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/): 7 <s>15</s> <s>19</s>

When using the little driver.

```
(:'r s) ; redfine read in the read-eval-print-loop
```

As a standalone expression without a driver: 15

```
((:'L(\()(L))))     ; setq a loop function and execute it
```

Usage: `echo '((\(L)(L))(\()(L)))' | jitbf zozotez.bf`

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>58</s> <s>55</s> 51

<s>Wow... longer than the C one. There's got to be a better way.</s> Still a tad long, but at least it beats the C solution!

```python
import time;t=time.time;u=t()+input()
while t()<u:1
```

Comment: Haha, I love your first sentence. Personally I consider a C answer as the par.

Comment: @ace (Barely) Fixed!

Comment: Now the other C solution beats yours!

Comment: @ace Ah, I give up, At least this one is portable! :P (I actually looked at sigalrm earlier, but it's just too expensive to set up and use signals... Python can be rather wordy when its libs are required :[)

Answer (score 3):

### x86_64 assembly on Linux - 146 (source), 42 (assembled code)

The NASM minified source (146 bytes):

```asm
xor rdi,rdi
mov rcx,[rsp+16]
mov rcx,[rcx]
l:
sub cl,'0'
jl k
imul rdi,10
movsx rdx,cl
add rdi,rdx
ror rcx,8
jmp l
k:
mov rax,37
syscall
s:
jmp s
```

Accepts a parameter on the command line specifying the number of seconds to run in the range (0, 9999999]; can be interrupted with the usual Ctrl-C.

You can assemble it with

```
nasm -f elf64 -o stress.o stress.asm && ld -o stress stress.o
```

In theory it would be necessary to add a `global _start` followed by a `_start:` label at the beginning, but `ld` manages to fix it by itself with little fuss.

The corresponding machine code (42 bytes):

```
00000000  48 31 ff 48 8b 4c 24 10  48 8b 09 80 e9 30 7c 11  |H1.H.L$.H....0|.|
00000010  48 6b ff 0a 48 0f be d1  48 01 d7 48 c1 c9 08 eb  |Hk..H...H..H....|
00000020  ea b8 25 00 00 00 0f 05  eb fe                    |..%.......|
0000002a
```

(generated with `nasm` adding the `BITS 64` directive)

A somewhat more readable version:

```asm
global _start

_start:
    xor rdi,rdi
    mov rcx,[rsp+16]
    mov rcx,[rcx]
argparse:
    sub cl,'0'
    jl alarm
    imul rdi,10
    movsx rdx,cl
    add rdi,rdx
    ror rcx,8
    jmp argparse
alarm:
    mov rax,37
    syscall
loop:
    jmp loop
```

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, 2 characters

`%0`

In essence, the program constantly starts itself over and over.  Your results may vary, due to processor task allocation priority, but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

## Java - <s>154 148</s> 186

Weird error ate my `Thread.sleep()` part

```java
public class Z{public static void main(String[]a) throws Exception{new Thread(){public void run(){for(;;);}.start();Thread.sleep(Byte.valueOf(a[0])*1000);System.exit(0);}}
```

and a more readable version:

```java
public class Z {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                for (;;)
                    ;
            }
        }.start();
        Thread.sleep(Byte.valueOf(a[0]) * 1000);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Spawns a `new Thread` with a nice endless loop (`for(;;);`) then on main thread a `thread.sleep()` and a `System.exit(0)` after timeout to exit; ctrl-c exits, too on cmdline
wasnt able to shorthand that `exit()`. crashing wont work;

Answer (score 2):

## Go, <s>215</s> <s>212</s> 193 bytes (full)

```
package main
import(."runtime"
f"flag"
."strconv"
."time")
func main(){f.Parse()
c:=NumCPU()*2
t,_:=Atoi(f.Arg(0))
GOMAXPROCS(c)
for;c>0;c--{go(func(){for{Now()}})()}
<-After(Duration(t)*1e9)}
```

Bonus, stresses all CPU's.

The `Now()` in the loop is there to kick in the scheduler, `Now` was the shortest function name I could find in my namespace

If I run `go fmt` the size increases to <s>286</s> <s>277</s> 254 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## C# - 178 characters

```
using A=System.DateTime;class P{static void Main(string[]a){var b=A.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(a[0]));System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0,1<<30,(i,l)=>{if(A.Now>b)l.Stop();});}}
```

And more readable:

```
using A = System.DateTime;
{ 
    class P 
    {
        static void Main(string[] a)
        { 
            var b = A.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(a[0]));
            System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 1 << 30, (i, l) => 
            {
                if (A.Now > b)l.Stop(); 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thats 178 chars in C# and uses all cores.

The only weakness that it is always ending because of the 1<<30 integer limit.

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>18</s> <s>54</s> 50 bytes

To produce 100% load for all CPU cores.

```
for($s=date;($s|% AddS* "$args")-ge(date)){sajb{}}
```

- The script takes a time in seconds as argument.
- `| AddS*` is [the shortcut](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) for `.AddSeconds()` method.
- `sajb` is the alias for `Start-Job` cmdlet.

Comment: How does this satisfy requirement 2 (`must take a numeric input, representing the number seconds the stress-test should run`)?

Answer (score 1):

C#, 118

```c#
using a=System.DateTime;class b{static void Main(string[]c){var d=a.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(c[0]));while(d>a.Now){}}}
```

Uncompressed

```c#
using a = System.DateTime;
class b 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] c) 
    {
        var d = a.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(c[0]));
        while (d > a.Now) { } 
    } 
}
```

This requires a number as an argument which is the number of seconds to run.  It will use 100% of one core for that much time or until crtl+c.  I'm pretty sure this is as small as C# will go with its verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

### Linux sh and standard utilities, 14

Recent gnu coreutils includes a `timeout` utility which is helpful:

```
 timeout $1 yes
```

Comment: Nowhere near 100% CPU for me; it's throttled way too much by having to print I think...is there another command?

Comment: `timeout $1 yes :|sh` - 19 is probably the best you can do and get 100% utilisation.  Tempted to steal this for my answer, but I'll be sportsman-like :)

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab - 19

`tic;while toc<5;end`

Replace `5` with desired execution time.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash: 19 chars

```bash
function f(){ f;};f
```

Answer (score 1):

## Assembly: 16 bytes

```asm
_start:jg _start
```

Edit: Having not noticed the requirement to take a numeric input, i'm going to claim it does take one on the commandline, but ignores it =)

Comment: This takes a numeric input for the number of seconds the test runs? It looks to me like it simply loops infinitely. Whatever it is, remember to add an explanation in your answer.

Comment: Oh... totally read past that part of the question :/

Answer (score 1):

## EcmaScript 6:

```js
z=z=>{while(1)z()};_=i=>(i+=1,i-=1,i++,i--,--i,++i,i<<=2,i>>=2,i+=0|Math.round(1+Math.random())&1|0,z(x=>setInterval(x=>z(x=>new Worker('data:text/javascript,'+_.toSource()),5))));setInterval(x=>z(x=>_(...Array(i=9e3).map((x,z)=>z*3/2*2/4*4e2>>2<<2))),5)
```

This will use 100% of the CPU on a single-core machine, and with Firefox, it has the added bonus that Firefox keeps using up more and more memory; the whole interface locks up and the only way to stop it is to kill Firefox in the task manager.

Answer (score 1):

## DOS Batch - 5 bytes

```
%0|%0
```

## DOS Batch - 8 bytes

```
%0|%0&%0
```

Second is a translation of the infamous sh forkbomb.

Ctrl+C breaks the program (unless you've tweaked the settings a little).

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 88 characters

```
class S{public static void main(String[]a){for(long i=0;i<Long.valueOf(a[0]);){i=i+1;}}}
```

This allows for 2⁶³-1 loops.

#### More Readable Version

```
class S {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
      for (long i = 0; i < Long.valueOf(a[0]);) { i = i + 1; }
}
```

## C# - 87 characters

```
class S{public static void Main(string[]a){for(long i=0;i<long.Parse(a[0]);){i=i+1;}}}
```

#### More Readable Version

```
class S {
public static void Main(string[] a) {
    for(long i = 0;i < long.Parse(a[0]);i++) { i = i + 1; }
}
}
```

[image: The program pegging the core]

(This is on a 4 core system)

Comment: OP asked for 100%

Comment: The OP also specified that you only need to peg one core. It can go to 25% (which is 100% of 1 core).

Comment: Not to be picky but your image shows 24.89% not 25%

Comment: True. It depends on what's happening on that core. If nothing is happening on the core, it will use the full 25%.

Answer (score 1):

## perl, 23 bytes

I can't figure out how to paste a literal control-T here, so I've typed $^T instead, but either works (the literal is 1 char shorter at 23 bytes):

```
$e=$^T+<>;1 until$e<time
```

$^T is just the time the interpreter started, so you can basically read that as time() since it is the first thing we calculate.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 30

I found this old puzzle interesting, I hope it's OK to post an answer to an old question.  I just couldn't let the C answers beat Python.  ;)

`sum(range(int(input())*2**26))`

This needs tuned for different CPUs, but I don't think that violates the OP... `sum(range(2**27))` pegs one of *my* 2.8GHz i7 cores for about a second.  :)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Posting answers to old questions is perfectly acceptable here, however as far as I see this answer does not full fill the requirement `must produce 100% CPU load until aborted`.

Comment: Thanks!  :)  On my machine, this code produces 100% load on a single core, and I can abort it like any other script by pressing Ctrl-C or killing the parent process (e.g., by closing the terminal window) or etc.  Note also requirement 2: `must take a numeric input, representing the number seconds the stress-test should run`.  So that the code needs to take user input somehow and self-limit accordingly, as well as just peg a CPU.  This is the part I found most interesting about the puzzle...

Comment: You're right, thanks for the clarification.