# Happy Birthday to Me!

Tags: code-golf

### Happy birthday to Me!

Write a program that prints `Happy birthday to me!` on its birthday.

1. The program's birthday is the creation, last modification or compilation time of the program (you choose), and must not be hard-coded.
2. The date you use as the birthday must not be affected by the program's invocation or execution in any way. You can't modify your birthday.
3. For extra credit (-15% byte count), print `Happy birthday to you!` on your birthday (hard coded), [if it doesn't coincide](http://xkcd.com/680/) with the program's. Or use some celebrity's birthday and get -14%.
4. It must print only this, and not print anything on any other day.
5. Count bytes, in UTF-8.
6. Use the Gregorian calendar.

Good luck and happy birthday (to the newborn programs).

P.S.
Following Izkata's comment, if you print `Happy birthday to Mel` on [Mel Kaye](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html)'s birthday, you get 20% off. But you have to provide a credible source that it's this date.

Comment: what if i print it on my bday and a celebrity's bday? :P

Comment: @TeunPronk, You can't do both. Either use your own birthday, or a celebrity's (or none, and give up the extra credit).

Comment: that bonus is a killer - I think the choice between dates and messages is too complex for the 15% to be worth the effort for getting the smallest code size

Comment: Agreed; in all attempts I've done to incorporate the bonus the score only goes up (where lower == beter).

Comment: @TeunPronk: Only Jon Skeet can :P

Comment: Is this a code-golf? If so, you should add that tag.

Comment: I saw this in the Hot Questions sidebar and read "Happy Birthday to [Mel](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/story-of-mel.html)"...

Comment: @nyuszika7h http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/21285/revisions It was tagged codegolf but was changed to challenge. Possibly because of a semi-complex scoring system

Comment: @PeterTaylor, why retag to code-challenge? The winner is the lowest byte count, which makes it code golf.

Comment: Point 3 makes the winner not lowest byte count, and disqualifies it from being [tag:code-golf]. I meant to mention this when it was in the sandbox, but I may have forgotten.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Huh? Awarding various kinds of score bonuses for extra features is pretty common for [tag:code-golf] questions, and I've never before seen anyone claim that it would disqualify a question from using that tag, as long as the *primary* scoring criterion is code length.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "some celebrity" part. How many celebrities are allowed in the program, and can you subtract 14% for each of them?

Comment: @MrLister, one celebrity.

Comment: @Izkata Cannot up-vote that enough.

Comment: @Izkata, Updated the question in honor of Mel.

Comment: @ugoren If Mel Kaye himself post an answer (very unlikely), what it should output in his birthday?

Comment: @Victor, whatever answer he'd post, I'll automatically accept.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, the tag wiki excerpt for [tag:code-golf] says "A competition which scores on a mixture of source length and some other criterion should be tagged [code-challenge] instead." I've been retagging questions on this basis for a while now, and no-one's complained before.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Wait, are you on a one man crusade to change all [code-golf] questions to [code-challenge] if they say "X points off if you also ..." ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: [I just started a meta discussion on this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/should-bonuses-be-allowed-for-code-golf-questions), feel free to join in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### PHP <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> <s>65</s> 60

Many thanks to the superb suggestions from [Tim Seguine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21285/happy-birthday-to-me/21294#comment43024_21294):

```
<?date(dm,getlastmod())-date(dm)&&die?>Happy birthday to me!
```

### Sneaky PHP: <s>46</s> <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 40

Using [Phil H's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21291/4040) and again [Tim Seguine's suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21285/happy-birthday-to-me/21294#comment43024_21294):

```
<?touch(__FILE__)?>Happy birthday to me!
```

Comment: Doesn't it include the year in the comparison? if so, it only works on the 0th birthday.

Comment: @ugoren You're right! Thanks for the correction. 2 bytes saved.

Comment: If "doesn't preint anything" in the rules is construed to mean standard output, then you could win 4 bytes by removing the `''` around the `dm` strings. It generated a warning, but I believe it gets sent to standard error if error reporting is on.

Comment: And the equals sign and the semicolon are not necessary for the touch version.

Comment: `<?date(dm,stat(__FILE__)[9])-date(dm)&&die?>Happy birthday to me!`

Comment: @TimSeguine Thanks for your suggestions! I've incorporated them into my answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course it is fine, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it. If your feeling overly thankful, then feel free to upvote my answers to other questions. ;)

Comment: I found another mod that trimmed it down to 60, ;) instead of `stat(__FILE__)[9]` use `getlastmod()`

Comment: @TimSeguine Thanks again. I've also seen that function in the manual, but I didn't know that it accepts 0 parameters :)

Answer (score 13):

## bash - 65

```
[ `date +%d%m -r $0` = `date +%d%m` ]&&echo Happy birthday to me!
```

Thanks to *ugoren*, *ace* and *nyuszika7h* for help.

Comment: I think you can escape the `!` with `\!` so you don't need the quotes and save 1 char.

Comment: Actually I had the quotes since I thought echo would require them for the spaces. I took them out and did not escape the exclamation mark and it still worked. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You only need to escape `!` in interactive shells, not scripts.

Comment: You can save two characters by using `[` and `]` instead of `[[` and `]]`.

Comment: Does it work when the year isn't the same as the creation date?

Comment: @ugoren: damn I feel stupid now :D

Comment: @nyuszika7h I cannot get that working

Comment: Using `[ ]` instead of `[[ ]]` should work, are you sure you have spaces between the square brackets and the backticks?

Comment: ah, now that the output format is numerical (not 18-02-2014 but 182) the single square brackets seem to work

Comment: Don't 11/1 and 1/11 get mixed up?

Comment: @ugoren: damn you are good at bug hunting. Fortunately 11/1 and 1/11 won't get mixed up as both %d and %m actually prepend a zero when the value is a single digit - I end up checking 0111 and 1101 for equality. I hope this works for all cases but I'm not sure.

Comment: @shiona, Leading zeros are good (unless they mean octal numbers, but I don't think bash does it).

Comment: You can use `=` for comparing strings.

Answer (score 6):

## C# 198.05 (233 - 15%)

```c#
using s=System;class P{static void Main(){string t=s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"),b="1202";if(s.IO.File.GetCreationTime(typeof(P).Assembly.Location).ToString("Mdd")==t|b==t)s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to "+(b==t?"you!":"me!"));}}
```

Formatted:

```c#
using s = System;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string t = s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"), b = "1202";
        if (s.IO.File.GetCreationTime(typeof(P).Assembly.Location).ToString("Mdd") == t | b == t)
            s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to " + (b == t ? "you!" : "me!"));
    }
}
```

## 191 (No bonus)

```c#
using s=System;class P{static void Main(){if(s.IO.File.GetCreationTime(typeof(P).Assembly.Location).ToString("Mdd")==s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"))s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to me!");}}
```

## 181,05 (213 - 15%)

With some additional instructions (you need to compile this to `b.exe` and run it from the directory the executable is in) I can get it down to this:

```c#
using s=System;class P{static void Main(){string t=s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"),b="1202";if(s.IO.File.GetCreationTime("b.exe").ToString("Mdd")==t|b==t)s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to "+(b==t?"you!":"me!"));}}
```

## 171 (No bonus)

Same instructions as above, this time only printing a message on it's own birthday (so no -15% bonus).

```c#
using s=System;class P{static void Main(){if(s.IO.File.GetCreationTime("b.exe").ToString("Mdd")==s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"))s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to me!");}}
```

Comment: You could save few bytes in the bonus ones by adding `,b="1202"==t` after you get the date string and using that instead.

Comment: Thanks! Though "few bytes" turns out to be one... or am I missing something? **Edit** Ah, I see; you said `,b="1202"==t` but the `==t` part is not possible since that evaluates to a bool and the other var is a string. You cannot (AFAIK that is) use two different types in one "var" declaration.

Comment: Ah, okay. It's been a while since I've used C#. My bad.

Comment: You could shorten the simpler version by comparing dates, not strings. This mens using something like `CreationTime.Date == DateTime.Today`.

Comment: That would only work for today/this year/birthday 0. How would that work for other years?

Answer (score 5):

## Java - 275 - 15% = 233.75 with bonus / 237 without bonus

With bonus:

```java
import java.util.*;class L{public static void main(String[]y){int s=f(new Date());String j="Happy birthday to ";System.out.print(s==f(new Date(new java.io.File("L.class").lastModified()))?j+"me!":s==183?j+"you!":"");}static int f(Date d){return d.getMonth()*40+d.getDate();}}
```

Without the bonus:

```java
import java.util.*;class L{public static void main(String[]y){if(f(new Date())==f(new Date(new java.io.File("L.class").lastModified())))System.out.print("Happy birthday to me!");}static int f(Date d){return d.getMonth()*40+d.getDate();}}
```

I was born in April, 23rd.

Comment: Happy birthday **to**, not **for** ;-) Just saved you another byte :-)

Comment: Also, the newline (`\n`) is not required AFAIK which saves you another 4 bytes ;-)

Comment: Yeah... I should stop shooting my own foot :P You're welcome ;)

Comment: Does it work when the creation year isn't the same as the current year?

Comment: @ugoren Yes, the `return d.getMonth()*40+d.getDate();` do not uses the year (so it is thrown away). And I just retested this to be sure that I was not missing something.

Comment: @Victor, right, I missed `f` and though you just compare dates.

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab: 66

```
t=dir('f.m');if strncmp(t.date,date,5),'Happy birthday to me!',end
```

File name has to be 'f.m'

Comment: On *your* birthday it should say "Happy birthday to **you**!" :-)

Comment: @RobIII:Oops, you'r right, I didn't read carefully enough. Will remove the second version. Thanks!

Comment: I assume `strncmp(x, y, 5)` compares dates like `28-12-2013`'s first 15 characters (being `28-12` e.g. dec. 28th). Does this also work when the user's locale settings are `yyyy/mm/dd` for example? Does Matlab default to `dd-mm-yyyy` always? (Just curious). **Edit** Nevermind: [found it!](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html). It seems it does. It wouldn't matter anyway for `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` since both left and right operand would use the same format anyway and both 5 leftmost chars would match anyway; as long as the year is never leading.

Comment: Why do you need the variable `t`? Doesn't `dir('f.m').date` work?

Comment: @ugoren: `t` is necessary to make `dir` return the file attributes (otherwise it would it would just return all files in the directory that match `'f.m'`). Furthermore, `t` is necessary to access the `date` field.

Comment: @H.Muster, I'm afraid I don't get it. I really don't know Matlab. In most languages, `t=dir('f.m');t.date` is equivalent to `dir('f.m').date`.

Comment: First, matlab does not support `dir('f.m').date` and secondly, the behavior of `dir` depending on whether you call it as `dir('f.m')` or  `t = dir('f.m')`. Please see http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/dir.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty proud of this little trick to save a few bytes on the message. I hope it will be included in other answers. I was the first to think of this!

## Python

105 characters, no extra credit. Save the file as "happy birthday to me" and run. Runs in GMT only, and "birthday" is defined as the date of your birth, not it's anniversary (also often call "birthday").

```
import sys,os,time
if (int(os.stat(*sys.argv).st_atime/86400)==int(time.time()/86400)):print sys.argv[0]
```

For it to work, save this as "happy birthday to me" and run `python "happy birthday to me"`

Note: of course, the all but a small bootstrap could be in the filename, making any arbitrarily large code reduce down to the bootstrap. Normally I would consider this "cheating". However, "happy birthday to me" is not an unreasonable filename - it describes what the program does, much better than some programs (e.g. "python"), so in this case I'm going to allow it :)

Comment: I think relying on the file name is cheating (though I didn't forbid it explicitly). If it's allowed, why not just write `eval(sys.argv[0])`?

Comment: And I didn't bother to define a birthday, but it's [a day that comes once a year when a person celebrates the anniversary of their birth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday), not the exact day when you were born.

Comment: ugoren: I did mention that in my note at the bottom (which pre-dates your comment). `However, "happy birthday to me" is not an unreasonable filename - it describes what the program does, much better than some programs (e.g. "python"), so in this case I'm going to allow it`

Answer (score 2):

### Batch - 37 Bytes

Stealing the method used by one of the Bash answers..

```
@echo.>>%0&echo Happy birthday to me!
```

**Other method - 145 Bytes**

```
@for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=/ " %%a in ("%date%")do @for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%c in ("%~t0")do @if %%a%%b==%%c%%d @echo Happy Birthday to me!
```

Answer (score 2):

**GNU COBOL** with -free, **204**

```
PROGRAM-ID.B.DATA DIVISION.WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
1 A PIC XXXX/XX.
1 B PIC X(5).
1 C PIC X(21).
PROCEDURE DIVISION.ACCEPT A FROM DATE
ACCEPT C
MOVE WHEN-COMPILED TO B
IF A(3:5) = B OR "12/09" DISPLAY C.
```

I break the rules about the celebrity, so no bonus there...

The text produced is user-input (requested when run). If that is not good-to-go, then the line defining `C` needs to be deleted, as does `ACCEPT C`, and `DISPLAY C` must become  `DISPLAY "HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO ME!"`, for an extra seven characters.

`WHEN-COMPILED` is a special-register containing compile date/time which is available to the program (always handy, you can know you have the correct version). It is truncated in the `MOVE` because the rest isn't needed. `DATE` is the current date - this one is yymmdd.

The `/` in the definition of A is an insertion editing symbol, since the compile-date contains slashes. An extra character, but eases the compare.

[Celebrity = Grace Hopper](http://www.google.com/doodles/grace-hoppers-107th-birthday)

Answer (score 1):

#### Powershell - 127

```
if ((gci $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).lastwritetime.ToString("MMdd") -eq (get-date).ToString("MMdd")){"happy birthday to me!"}
```

#### For the 15% bonus - 151 bytes, less 15% = 128.4

```
$r=@{"0308"="you";(gci $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).lastwritetime.ToString("MMdd")="me"}[(get-date).tostring("MMdd")]
if($r){"Happy birthday to $r!"}
```

Comment: I'm no powershell expert, but this will only work in the current year? What what when the "program" has it's 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. birthday?

Comment: You can remove the `write` command - With just `"happy birthday to me!"` it will print it out.

Comment: Your quite right. I should know that.

Comment: @Robill - oops. That's what comes of writing something when I'm distracted by something else and using codegolf as procrastination. Fixed (not that it's got a chance of winning, mind).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript

### Node.js, 156 bytes

```
b=new Date(require("fs").statSync(__filename).mtime);d=new Date();b.getDate()==d.getDate()&&b.getMonth()==d.getMonth()&&console.log("Happy birthday to me!")
```

Uses the file's modification time.

Comment: beating you by 56 bytes so far =P

Comment: I get a runtime error when I run yours, but the match approach is definitely much cleverer. Fix the error and you've got my upvote. ;)

Comment: Can you quote the error and your OS? I guess it's just not crossplatform.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 69 characters/bytes

```
puts'Happy birthday to me!'if(Time.new-File.atime($0))%31536000<86400
```

`31536000` is the number of seconds in a year, and `86400` is the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: Unfortunately, only works correctly for maximum of seven years or so, until you run into the first leap year after the atime.

Comment: Also says "happy birthday" on the morning after your birthday, and doesn't say happy birthday the morning of your birthday before your birth time.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby - <s>80</s> <s>103</s> 87 bytes

```
m=File.mtime $0
t=Time.now
puts"Happy birthday to me!"if t.month==m.month&&t.day==m.day
```

---

### Ruby - <s>123</s> <s>115</s> <s>135</s> 121 - 15% = <s>104.55</s> <s>97.75</s> <s>114.75</s> 102.85 points

```
t=Time.now
{me:File.mtime($0),you:Time.at(36e5)}.map{|n,d|puts"Happy birthday to #{n}!"if t.month==d.month&&t.day==d.day}
```

Might be a little longer or shorter depending on where your birthday falls in the year, and the shortest way to represent that. For mine, that's `36e5` (seconds since epoch; time zone dependent).

---

Does Mel **Gibson** count? Here's a 138 byte - 35% bonus = **89.7-point** program that celebrates itself, me, and Mel!

```
t=Time.now
{me:File.mtime($0),you:Time.at(36e5),Mel:Time.at(2e5)}.map{|n,d|puts"Happy birthday to #{n}!"if t.month==d.month&&t.day==d.day}
```

Comment: Your code fails on leap years, for dates after February.

Comment: @ugoren right you are. Fixed that, but lost a lot of points :(

Comment: But now I've reclaimed most of those! =)

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell - 105 bytes

```
if('{0:M}'-f(gi $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition).creationtime-eq(date -f M)){'Happy birthday to me!'}
```

Ungolfed:

```
if('{0:M}' -f (gi $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition).creationtime -eq (date -f M)){
  'Happy birthday to me!'
}
```

The bonus isn't worth it, I can only get 117.5.

Answer (score 0):

### TI-BASIC, 68 bytes

```
If Ans=0:getDate→G:0:G=G:If getDate=G:Disp "HAPPY BIRTHDAY TO ME!"
```

Remember, these tokens are one byte: `If , Ans, →, Disp`. `getDate` is two bytes. All other one-character symbols are one byte.

Comment: Are you sure that's UTF-8?

Comment: OP explicitly states you should use UTF-8. That's 66 characters and 68 bytes.

Comment: If you want to claim it's 46 bytes, write it in 46 bytes. As it is now, it's 68 bytes.

Comment: According to the token sizes in a standard TI-Basic environment it is 55 bytes, but as plain text yea its 68. Also technically there does not have to be a " at the end so that could save a byte.

Answer (score 0):

## PureBasic

### Without Bonus - 142

```
If Bool(FormatDate("%dd%mm",Date())=FormatDate("%dd%mm",GetFileDate(ProgramFilename(),0)))
MessageRequester("","Happy birthday To me!")
EndIf
```

### With Bonus - 218 - 15% = 185.3

```
Dim s$(2)
s$(1)="me"
s$(2)="you"
m$="%dd%mm"
d$=FormatDate(m$,Date())
i=Bool(d$=FormatDate(m$,GetFileDate(ProgramFilename(),0)))|(Bool(d$="2301")<<1)
If i=0:End:EndIf
MessageRequester("","Happy birthday To "+s$(i)+"!")
```

Answer (score 0):

### C# 191 no bonus

```
using s=System;class P{static void Main(){if(s.IO.File.GetCreationTime(typeof(P).Assembly.Location).ToString("Mdd")==s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"))s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to me!");}}
```

formatted:

```
using s = System;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        if (s.IO.File.GetCreationTime(typeof(P).Assembly.Location).ToString("Mdd") == s.DateTime.Now.ToString("Mdd"))
            s.Console.Write("Happy birthday to me!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You use x only twice; `var x="MMdd";` + ToString(`x`) + ToString(`x`) = 15 whereas ToString(`"MMdd"`); + ToString(`"MMdd"`); only costs 12.

Comment: Also, a newline is not required so `WriteLine()` can be shortened to `Write()`. With above and this change in place you have the exact same solution as I do ;-)

Comment: You should update the score too, which is 193 now. And you can get it down to 191 by shaving two M's off * [hint](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21288/14039) * :P

Answer (score 0):

## J 79

```
 echo((6!:0'')(('',:'Happy birthday to me!'){~])@:-:&(1 2&{)&:>])1{,1!:0{:4!:3''
```

#### Bonus version120 - 15% = 102

Do I get extra credit for also printing both when both are having their birthday?

```
echo((2 6$(6!:0 '') , 0 2 7)(' ','Happy birthday to ',"2 1]3 5$'you! me!  both!'){~#.@:(-:&(1 2&{)"1)&:>])1{,1!:0{:4!:3''
```

Explanation (right to left):

```
last =: {:4!:3''     NB. Take the last script run (i.e. the file itself)
time =: 1{,1!:0 last NB. the modification time is the second element in that file's listing
```

The central verb of the [train](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dictf.htm)

```
unbox_both =: &:>      NB. unboxes left and right argument
match  =: -:&(1 2&{)"1 NB. for each date given, left and right, compare them
to_int =: #.           NB. convert boolean to int
from   =: {~           NB. from the left array, take element right.

NB. H contains messages an empty row, appended to all combinations of messages. 
H =: (' ','Happy birthday to ',"2 1]3 5$'you! me!  both!')

V =: (H from to_int)@:match unbox_both NB. after unboxing and comparing, 
                                       NB. select the according message
```

The left tine for the central train:

```
dates=: (2 6$(6!:0 '') , 0 2 7) NB. the current date, and the relevant fields of my birthday.

NB. Combining the bricks:
echo (dates V ]) time           NB. output the monads result on time.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java - 196

This differs from the other Java submission by using Strings, shaving 41 characters off in the process. It uses String.format("%tj") to format a java.util.Date or a long as a day-of-year String, and then compares these two Strings.

```java
class Z{public static void main(String[]y){if("".format("%tj",new java.util.Date()).equals("".format("%tj",new java.io.File("Z.class").lastModified())))System.out.print("Happy birthday to me!");}}
```

Formatted:

```java
class Z
{
    public static void main(String[] y)
    {
        if ("".format("%tj", new java.util.Date()).equals("".format("%tj", new java.io.File("Z.class").lastModified())))
            System.out.print("Happy birthday to me!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Day of year doesn't work well with leap years.

Comment: @ugoren I agree. However, since the contest is currently running and we're at Feb. 20th. the compilation dat should be fine for a few days and not cause a problem following years. When compiling after Feb. 28th there will be a (future) problem indeed.

Comment: If I were compiling after February 28th I could change the String format to "%tm%td" at a six point character cost

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript (node.js) - 100 bytes**

```
(require('fs').fstatSync(4).mtime+1).match(Date().substr(4,6))&&console.log('Happy birthday to me!')
```

Answer (score 0):

**vb.net ~161c**

This will print the celebration message to all whose birthday it is.

```
Module M
Sub Main
For Each b In{({"1705","Alan"}),({"2012","You"}),({FileDateTime(Process.GetCurrentProcess.MainModule.FileName).ToString("ddMM"),"Me"})}
If b(0)=Now.ToString("ddMM") Then Console.WriteLine("Happy Birthday To {0}!",b(1))
Next
End Sub
End Module
```

Alan => Alan Kaye

Score: 253c (-33c vb.net min) = 220 - 15% (my birthday bonus) = 187c - 14% (Celeb Birthday) = 160.82 ~161c  or 220c - 29% = 156.2 ~157c

Comment: You can get a bonus for your birthday OR a celebrity. Not both.

Comment: @ugoren Scoring doesn't state it's an exclusive or, so I'm using the logical meaning of or.

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 82 bytes

> see also answers from [Chris J](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21306/80745) and [SpellingD](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/21431/80745)

```powershell
"Happy birthday to me!"|?{(gv My* -v|% M*|% p*h|gci|% l*w*e|% D*r)-eq(date|% D*r)}
```

where

```powershell
gv My* -v|% M*|% p*h|gci|% l*w*e|% D*r
```

is the combinations of [shortcuts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111526/80745) and [aliases](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases) for the expression:

```powershell
Get-Valiable MyInvocation -value|% MyCommand|% Path|Get-ChildItem|% LastWritetime|% DayOfYear
```

that equivalent a canonical form:

```powershell
(Get-ChildItem $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).LastWritetime.DayOfYear
```

---

## Powershell, 119 bytes - 14% = 102.34 Points

```powershell
filter e{$_-eq(date|% D*r)}$('me'|?{gv My* -v|% M*|% p*h|gci|% l*w*e|% D*r|e}
'Prof'|?{3|e})|%{"Happy birthday to $_!"}
```

At [January 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._R._R._Tolkien), the script display `Happy birthday to Prof!`. If this script is saved on January 3, two greetings will be displayed.