# Resolving the Date Format Dispute

Tags: code-golf, string

The formatting order of dates is one of the most complex and divisive issues the world faces today. Some of us vehemently argue that Month/Day/Year is appropriate, considering that's how we say dates out loud. Others loudly proclaim that Day/Month/Year is best, because it puts the terms in ascending order of the duration they represent.

Enough is enough. Computers can resolve this dispute simply and fairly. Your code, a complete function or program, will take a date string delimited by slashes, e.g. `12/1/2015`. Note this is the exact format, without leading zeroes and with a four-digit year at the end.

- If it's *definitely* Month/Day/Year, e.g. `10/31/1998`, output a text representation of that date in this exact format, with the full month name, day, and year: `October 31, 1998`
- If it's *definitely* Day/Month/Year, e.g. `25/12/1989`, output the same sort of text representation: `December 25, 1989`.
- If it's ambiguous whether it's Month/Day/Year or Day/Month/Year, output a date that resolves the ambiguity by combining the two possible dates as follows:

  1. Create a new month name by taking the first half of the name of the **earlier** month and append the second half of the **later** month. For months with odd length, the first half gets the extra letter. To be explicit, the first halves of the months are `Janu`, `Febr`, `Mar`, `Apr`, `Ma`, `Ju`, `Ju`, `Aug`, `Septe`, `Octo`, `Nove`, and `Dece` and the second halves are therefore `ary`, `uary`, `ch`, `il`, `y`, `ne`, `ly`, `ust`, `mber`, `ber`, `mber`, and `mber`.
  2. Calculate the day by averaging the two possible days, taking the floor when the average is not an integer.
  3. Output the text representation of this date, e.g. for `10/8/2011`, output `Augber 9, 2011`.

If the input date cannot be Month/Day/Year or Day/Month/Year (e.g. `13/13/2013` or even `2/30/2002`), any behavior is acceptable. This code golf, shortest code wins!

**Test cases:**

`10/31/1998` gives `October 31, 1998`

`25/12/1989` gives `December 25, 1989`

`10/8/2011` gives `Augber 9, 2011`

`8/5/1957` gives `Maust 6, 1957`

`9/12/2012` (oddly enough) gives `September 10, 2012`

`1/1/2000` gives `January 1, 2000`

Comment: Related - http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33033/has-my-milk-expired

Comment: For what it's worth, a lot of those who argue for day-month-year also say dates in that order. (Of course, Real Programmers argue for year-month-day).

Comment: Just to be sure: `without leading zeroes and with a four-digit year at the end` implies `year >= 1000`

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: +∞ for September 10, 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth - 156 bytes

Really bad code, and will need to use packed strings, but its something.

```
Kc"January February March April May June July August September October November December"dJhM.g>k12=GsMcz\/?<eJ32++@KthJdtP`,eJeGss[@VCcL2KStMPGdPt`,s.OPGeG
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Kc%22January+February+March+April+May+June+July+August+September+October+November+December%22dJhM.g%3Ek12%3DGsMcz%5C%2F%3F%3CeJ32%2B%2B%40KthJdtP%60%2CeJeGss%5B%40VCcL2KStMPGdPt%60%2Cs.OPGeG&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%2F31%2F1998%0A25%2F12%2F1989%0A10%2F8%2F2011%0A8%2F5%2F1957%0A9%2F12%2F2012%0A1%2F1%2F2000&debug=1).

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>341 304 298 288</s> 293 bytes

This uses a pure or anonymous function, that is, a function without its own name.

`DateString` returns an error message if the date is ambiguous. `Check`catches the ambiguity and sends the offending date to `DateList`, which transforms it into list of 3 integers (which it believes to be `{year, month, day}`). The month and day integers are sorted by size and used to determine the month and day as per the OP's instructions.

`Quiet` silences error printing.

```
t=StringSplit;v=ToString;x=t[#,"-"]&/@t["Janu-ary Febr-uary Mar-ch Apr-il Ma-y Ju-ne Ju-ly Aug-ust Septe-mber Octo-ber Nove-mber Dece-mber"];
Quiet@Check[#~DateString~{"MonthName"," ","DayShort",", ","Year"},
{m,n,o}=DateList@#;{p,q}=Sort@d[[2;;3]];x[[p,1]]<>x[[q,2]]<>" "<>v@Floor@Mean@{n,o}<>", "<>v@d[[1]]]&
```

---

```
t=StringSplit;v=ToString;x=t[#,"-"]&/@t["Janu-ary Febr-uary Mar-ch Apr-il Ma-y Ju-ne Ju-ly Aug-ust Septe-mber Octo-ber Nove-mber Dece-mber"];
Quiet@Check[#~DateString~{"MonthName"," ","DayShort",", ","Year"},
{m,n,o}=DateList@#;{p,q}=Sort@d[[2;;3]];x[[p,1]]<>x[[q,2]]<>" "<>v@Floor@Mean@{n,o}<>", "<>v@d[[1]]]& /@ 
{"10/31/1998","25/12/1989", "10/8/2011", "8/5/1957", "9/12/2012", "1/1/2012"}
```

> {"October 31, 1998", "December 25, 1989", "Augber 9, 2011", "Maust 6,
> 1957", "September 10, 2012", "January 1, 2012"}

Comment: I personally would love to see you eliminate that 0, but I'll let the votes fall as they may.

Comment: It now returns "January 1, 2012" as requested.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>311</s> <s>295</s> <s>282</s> <s>274</s> <s>246</s> 238 bytes

```
a=>(a=a.split`/`,b=c=>e(c).length+1>>1,d=' ',e=f=>new Date(99,a[+f]-1).toLocaleString('en',{month:'long'}),g=+a[0],h=+a[1],i=g>h,j=g>12,k=h>12,(j&&!k?e(1)+d+g:k&&!j?e(0)+d+h:e(i).slice(0,b(i))+e(1-i).slice(b(1-i))+d+((g+h)>>1))+', '+a[2])
```

**Edit:** Uses `toLocaleString` to generate month names. Change the locale to get results using month names in different locales!

**Edit 2:** Now generates two month names instead of all 12!

Ungolfed:

```
func = inp => (
    inp = inp.split `/`,
    get = arg => months(arg).length + 1 >> 1,
    space = ' ',
    months = key => new Date(99, inp[+key] - 1).toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long' }),
    tmp1 = +inp[0],
    tmp2 = +inp[1],
    first = tmp1 > tmp2,
    t1greater = tmp1 > 12,
    t2greater = tmp2 > 12,
    (t1greater && !t2greater ?
        months(1) + space + tmp1
    :
        t2greater && !t1greater ?
            months(0) + space + tmp2
        :
            months(first).slice(0, get(first)) + months(1 - first).slice(get(1 - first)) + space + ((tmp1 + tmp2) >> 1)
    )
    + ', ' + inp[2]
)
```

Example:

```
console.log(
    func('10/31/1998') + '\n' +
    func('25/12/1989') + '\n' +
    func('10/8/2011') + '\n' +
    func('8/5/1957') + '\n' +
    func('9/12/2012') + '\n' +
    func('1/1/2000')
);
```

*Thanks to: 

[@user81655](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46855/user81655), [274 => 246 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65578/#comment-158888) 

[@edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65), [246 => 238 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65578/#comment-159074)*

Comment: I haven't looked very thoroughly but here's a few improvements you could make:

change `Math.ceil(e[c].length/2)` to `(r=e[c].length/2)+r%1`,

`Array(2).fill().map((_,f)=>...)` to `f=>...` and every `e[n]` to `e(n)`,

`i=+(g>h)` to `i=g>h` and `e[i]` to `e[+i]`,

remove the unnecessary brackets in the last ternary operator,

Also, `newDate` should be `new Date`.

Comment: Avoid `Math.ceil` using `b=c=>e(c).length+1>>1`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 204

```
x=>(s=x=>x.split`/`,[a,b,y]=s(x).sort((a,b)=>a-b),(c=b)>12?c=a:b=a- -b>>1,s('/Janu/Febr/Mar/Apr/Ma/Ju/Ju/Aug/Septe/Octo/Nove/Dece')[a]+s('/ary/uary/ch/il/y/ne/ly/ust/mber/ber/mber/mber')[c]+` ${b}, `+y)
```

Test snippet:

```js
F=x=>(
  s=x=>x.split`/`,
  [a,b,y]=s(x).sort((a,b)=>a-b),
  (c=b)>12?c=a:b=a- -b>>1,
  s('/Janu/Febr/Mar/Apr/Ma/Ju/Ju/Aug/Septe/Octo/Nove/Dece')[a]
  +s('/ary/uary/ch/il/y/ne/ly/ust/mber/ber/mber/mber')[c]+` ${b}, `+y
)

console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

;['10/31/1998','25/12/1989','10/8/2011','8/5/1957','9/12/2012','1/1/2000']
.forEach(x=>console.log(x+' -> '+F(x)))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (290 bytes)

Similar to Ashwin Gupta's answer, but taking advantage of Python's calendar module to avoid writing out all of the month names.

```
import calendar as C
M,I,P,S,L,A=C.month_name,int,print," ",len,", "
def d(i):
 w=i.split("/")
 f,s,y=I(w[0]),I(w[1]),w[2]
 if(f>12):P(M[s]+S+w[0]+A+y)
 elif(s>12):P(M[f]+S+w[1]+A+y)
 else:l,h=min(f,s),max(f,s);P(M[l][:I(L(M[l])/2+.5)]+M[h][I(L(M[h])/2+.5):]+S+str(I((f+s)/2))+A+y)
```

Python 2 should trim a few bytes with integer division and losing the parentheses for `print`.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, <s>558</s> 554 bytes

A really, really, really horribly golfed example of how to do this in python. Sorry, I'm super bad at this golfing stuff `D:` . It works though. I'm sure there are plenty of ways to simplify this so let me know in the comments.
**Golfed:**

```
import math
def d(i):
 l=["","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]
 w=i.split('/')
 f=int(w[0])
 s=int(w[1])
 S=" "
 y=w[2]
 if(f>12):
  e=int(w[1])
  print(l[e]+S+w[0]+", "+y)
  elif(f<=12 and s>12):
   e=int(w[0])
   print(l[e]+S+w[0]+", "+y)
   else:
    if(f<s):
     o=l[f]
     t=l[s]
    else:
     o=l[s]
     t=l[f]
    o=o[0:int(math.ceil(len(o)/2))]
    t=t[int(math.ceil(len(t)/2)):len(t)]
    print(o+t+S +  str(math.floor((f + s)/2)) + ", " + y)
```

***Ungolfed***

```
import math
def d(i):
    l = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    w = i.split('/')
    f = int(w[0])
    s = int(w[1])
    y = w[2]
    if(f > 12):
        e = int(w[1])
        print(l[e] + " " + w[0] + ", " + y)

    elif(f <= 12 and s > 12):
         e = int(w[0])
         print(l[e] + " " + w[0] + ", " + y)
    else:
         if(f < s):
            o=l[f]
            t=l[s]
         else:
            o=l[s]
            t=l[f]
         o = o[0:int(math.ceil(len(o)/2))]
         t = t[int(math.ceil(len(t)/2)):len(t)]
         print(o+t+" " +  str(math.floor((f + s)/2)) + ", " + y)
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: put `S=" "` at the top, then replace every instance of `" "` with `S` -- that will shave off some bytes

Comment: there's a few unnecessary spaces after assignments (`e= int[...`, `o = o...`). also, it might prove adventageous to set often-used calls like `int` to single-letter uppercase vars

Comment: This has a few problems: it gives me one decimal place in the ambiguous case, and doesn't split the month names correctly: `10/8/2011` gives `Augober 9.0, 1957` and `8/5/1957` gives `Must 6.0, 1957`.

Comment: @Luke really? I tried your test cases and that worked, let me double check again. And it should be printing the numbers as ints because I type cast f and s to int.

Comment: @sysreq Ok thanks for the tips, Ill regolf it after school. What do you mean by setting often used calls to an uppercacse variable? How do I do that?

Comment: @Luke ok just tried it, seems to be working great for me. (See question body for a screen shot.) Just in case though, I'll copy/paste the code back in, maybe something got deleted or its an older version.

Comment: @Luke I just retried all of the test cases, they all work for me.

Comment: Here's 447 bytes: `from math import*
I=int
S=" "
C=","
L=len
P=print
def d(i):
 l=["","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];w=i.split('/');f=I(w[0]);s=I(w[1]);y=w[2]
 if f>12:e=I(w[1]);P(l[e]+S+w[0]+C+S+y)
 elif f<13and s>12:e=I(w[0]);P(l[e]+S+w[0]+C+S+y)
 else:
  if f<s:o=l[f];t=l[s]
  else:o=l[s];t=l[f];o=o[0:I(ceil(L(o)/2))];t=t[I(ceil(L(t)/2)):L(t)]
  P(o+t+S+str(floor((f+s)/2))+C+S+y)
`

Comment: @sysreq ok my mind is officially blown. I didn't know you could store functions to a variable. Thank you. I will edit that in. Also, could you do me a favor and try running my code (golfed one) and see if it's working like it should because Luke seems to be getting different results than me so I just want to see.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your program works as expected in all test cases: `d("8/5/1957") -> Maust 6, 1957`, `d("10/8/2011") -> Augber 9, 2011`

Comment: @sysreq yeah idk. Why it's different for him. Anyways, thanks again for the tips, it really helps not only for golfing but in general since I'm still new to Python. Also, I just realized I can remove my initial assignments of o and t and save 4 bytes by putting he array element directly in my splitter. I will make all of these changes this afternoon. Thanks to you the new byte count will be significantly less!

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <s>301</s> 294 bytes

```
function r($t){$e='return date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$o));';list($a,$b,$c)=explode('/',$t);$o=min($a,$b);$m=eval($e);$o=max($a,$b);$n=eval($e);echo(($a|$b)<13)?substr($m,0,ceil(strlen($m)/2)).substr($n,ceil(strlen($n)/2))." ".floor(($a+$b)/2).", $c":date("F j, Y",strtotime(($a>12)?"$b/$a/$c":$t));}
```

I thought I could compete with the Javascript answer. Oh well.

I think I could make it smaller and I don't like the code I used for the ambiguous dates. I think there is a better way to do it.

Ungolfed:

```
function r($t){
    // Eval'd code to reduce char count
    $e='return date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$o));';
    
    // Split the date
    list($a,$b,$c)=explode('/',$t);
    
    // Get the earliest month
    $o=min($a,$b);
    $m=eval($e);
    
    // Get the latest month
    $o=max($a,$b);
    $n=eval($e);
    
    // If ambiguous
    if ($a<13 && $b<13) {
        print substr($m,0,ceil(strlen($m)/2)).substr($n,ceil(strlen($n)/2))." ".floor(($a+$b)/2).", $c";
    }
    else {
        print date("F j, Y",strtotime(($a>12)?"$b/$a/$c":$t));
    }
}
```