# What is this date format?

Tags: code-golf, date

For Gregorian calendars, the date format varies from a country to another. There are three main formats recognized:

1. `YY-MM-DD` (big-endian)
2. `DD-MM-YY` (little-endian)
3. `MM-DD-YY` (middle-endian)

Your task is to write a program which, given an input string representing a date, output all the possible date formats by which this string can be interpreted as a date.

**Rules**

- The input date is in the format `xx-xx-xx`, where each field is two digits and zero-padded.
- The date is always valid (so you cannot get things like 14-13-17)
- The date is always at least one of the formats above (so you cannot get things like 17-14-11)
- Because we are in fact in a parallel world, **there are 31 days for every month of the year**, and consequently no leap years
- The date is between January 01, 2001 and December 31, 2099
- If there is only one format for the date, the code must print only it (only trailing newlines are allowed)
- If there are several formats for the date, they must be either separated by a comma, a space, a newline, or a combination of those
- You must output the exact name(s) of the format(s). Using distinct arbitrary values is not allowed.
- No leading or trailing characters others than a trailing space are allowed
- The output must be lowercase
- You are not allowed to use any built-in date or calendar functions
- The output formats do not have to be sorted

**Examples**

```
Input      Output
30-05-17   big-endian, little-endian
05-15-11   middle-endian
99-01-02   big-endian
12-11-31   big-endian, little-endian, middle-endian
02-31-33   middle-endian
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins. Explanations are encouraged.

Comment: You should probably add a test-case using February 31st to make sure answers support that weird case :P

Comment: Can we output any three distinct values for the three valid formats, or must it be those three exact strings?

Comment: `there are 31 days for every month of the year, and consequently no leap years` So this means any date library is effectively useless for this then?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yes, most date libraries are probably unusable.

Comment: Since the year is 01-99, does this mean no number in the date will ever be 0?

Comment: @ETHproductions It must be these three exact strings. I have updated the rules.

Comment: @BusinessCat Indeed, no number in the date will ever be zero.

Comment: Does the output have to be a string or can it be an array of the values or similar?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It has to be a string, you are not permitted to display square brackets or similar. I updated the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Does the output then have to be comma and space separated values or can I have only space separated? Can I also have leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/33033/has-my-milk-expired)

Comment: There are [many more formats](https://xkcd.com/1179/) out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 40 bytes

```
'-¡©2£13‹`®Á2£32‹*)˜“Œ±„¥„ê“#Ï’-„–ian’«»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@ue2jhoZVGhxYbGj9q2JlwaN3hRiDH2AjI0dI8PedRw5yjkw5tfNQw79BSIHF4FVBA@XD/o4aZukDuo4bJmYl5QM6h1Yd2//9vbKBrYKpraA4A)

**Explanation**

```
'-¡©                                      # split on "-" and store a copy in register
    2£13‹                                 # compare the first 2 elements to 13
         `                                # split as separate to stack
                                          # the bottom element is true if it is middle endian
                                          # the top value is true if it can be big/little
          ®Á                              # retrieve the list from register and rotate right
            2£32‹                         # compare the first 2 elements to 32
                 *                        # multiply with the result of the comparison to 13
                  )˜                      # wrap in a flattened list
                    “Œ±„¥„ê“#             # push the list ['middle', 'big', 'little']
                             Ï            # index into this with the flattened list
                                          # this leaves the types the date could be
                              ’-„–ian’«   # append "-endian" to each
                                       »  # join on newlines
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 123 bytes

```python
a,b,c=map(int,input().split('-'))
for a,b,c in[[b,c,'big'],[b,a,'little'],[a,b,'middle']]:print(c+'-endian')*(a<13)*(b<32),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HYxLDoMwDAX3PQU7x61T8VlR0ZMgFg6hlSUIEU3PHxxW80YavczkaH5vHI2ERBLiPxl8/uIqyYAFxNtnP6qrqiSMo5LAyRcm0s0EGqZ1KVoi2MT7otMrHvpo5gfYJXjhAHg3PDSdwg1di5Qz9L2tG1u3cAI)

---

### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), less input parsing, 123 bytes

```python
d=input()
for a,b,c in[[3,6,'big'],[3,0,'little'],[0,3,'middle']]:print(c+'-endian')*(int(d[a:a+2])<13)*(int(d[b:b+2])<32),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PchBDsIgEEDRvafobsAOCe1ETYg9CWEBpZpJ6tg0eH4qLtz9/2qeWLZPUfr0eO9dxIRzx@I94RUh8RMCftsirFzKurS1SAgvzrltcNvOUtTcg1kkcxTQZ9Uk@@hiPwZ9H@hPyaUf0aixViBr7MUMNzgA)

Comment: You're allowed to separate with newlines, so can remove the trailing `,`.

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>121</s> <s>119</s> <s>118</s> 112 bytes

Returns a space-delimited string with a trailing space.

```js
s=>['big','little','middle'].map((v,i)=>[b<13&c<32,b<13&a<32,a<13][i]?v+'-endian ':'',[a,b,c]=s.split`-`).join``
```

#### How?

We split the input into **a**, **b** and **c**. Because the date is guaranteed to be valid, we know for sure that **b** is less than 32. Therefore, it's enough to test whether **a** is less than 13 to validate the middle-endian format. Little-endian and big-endian formats require **b** to be less than 13 and another test on **a** and **c** respectively to validate the day.

Hence the 3 tests:

- Big-endian: **b < 13 & c < 32**
- Little-endian: **b < 13 & a < 32**
- Middle-endian: **a < 13**

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>['big','little','middle'].map((v,i)=>[b<13&c<32,b<13&a<32,a<13][i]?v+'-endian ':'',[a,b,c]=s.split`-`).join``

console.log(f("30-05-17")) // big-endian, little-endian
console.log(f("05-15-11")) // middle-endian
console.log(f("99-01-02")) // big-endian
console.log(f("12-11-31")) // big-endian, little-endian, middle-endian
console.log(f("02-31-33")) // middle-endian
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>240</s> <s>125</s> <s>116</s> 112 bytes

```
IFS=- read a b c<<<$1
d=-endian
((b<13))&&(((a<32))&&echo little$d;((c<32))&&echo big$d);((a<13))&&echo middle$d
```

Golfed.

Thanks to manatwork for some tips

Saved 9 bytes removing the verification for less than 32 in the middle-endian follwing Arnauld answer

Saved 4 bytes by using different variables instead of an array

[Test it!](https://tio.run/##TYuxCsIwEED3fsUNoVyGQGMQh6ar4OwXXO4OE6gp1P66cyS6uD0e7yV65dZu1/viYFcSIEjAMUbjB1mcVilUB8QUfbB2HBGRYjh1VM4brOU4VjUyI/K/T@VhxM69/o1f@ywivW6thclNZ@cv77o5Js76AQ)

Comment: There are a couple of [arithmetic related tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/15280) in [Tips for golfing in Bash](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/tips-for-golfing-in-bash). You could reduce it a bit: 
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/39Mt2FZXoSg1MUVBtygx0cbGRsWQK9VWNzUvJTMxj0tDIzHaMNbG0FhTU02tGsS1MTYCsVOTM/IVcjJLSnJSVVLByoxikaWSMtOB4rVgHYbGampgY5DkczNTUkBa////b2yga2Cqa2j@NS9fNzkxOSMVAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: Thank you @manatwork I have that question bookmarked is very useful, will golf it by it

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 180 bytes

```c#
t=(n,m)=>int.Parse(n)<13&int.Parse(m)<32;s=>{var a=s.Split('-');return$"{(t(a[1],a[2])?"big-endian":"")} {(t(a[1],a[0])?"little-endian":"")} {(t(a[0],a[1])?"middle-endian":"")}";};
```

Outputs with only space separated values, can also have leading and trailing spaces. Will update when the OP has clarified on that point if needed.

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
Func<string, string, bool> t = (n, m) => int.Parse(n) < 13 & int.Parse(m) < 32;

Func<string, string> f = s =>
{
    var a = s.Split('-');

    return $"{(t(a[1], a[2]) ? "big-endian" : "")} {(t(a[1], a[0]) ? "little-endian" : "")} {(t(a[0], a[1]) ? "middle-endian" : "")}";
};
```

Comment: I made the rule more clear: `No leading or trailing characters others than a trailing space are allowed`

Answer (score 1):

## Java 232 bytes

```
(String s)=>{String[]i=s.split("-");String e="-endian",b="big"+e,m="middle"+e,l="little"+e;int p=Integer.valueOf(i[0]);System.out.print(p<13?Integer.valueOf(i[1])<13?Integer.valueOf(i[2])<32?b+","+m+","+l:m+","+l:m:p<32?b+","+l:b);}
```

**Here's a nicer version**

```
String[] i = s.split("-");

String e = "-endian",
       b = "big" + e,
       m = "middle" + e,
       l = "little" + e;

int p = Integer.valueOf(i[0]);
```

I didn't really know how to format this part...

```
System.out.print(
        p < 13 ? Integer.valueOf(I[1]) < 13 ? Integer.valueOf(I[2]) < 32 ? b + "," + m + "," + l
                                                                         : m + "," + l
                                            : m 

               : p < 32 ? b + "," + l 
                        : b
);
```

Comment: Too many endians: `String e="-endian",b="big"+e,m="middle"+e,l="little"+e;`.

Comment: Good point, when I decided not to do that I was including an extra "String " in my byte count. @manatwork

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 151 Bytes

```php
[$a,$b,$c]=sscanf($argn,"%d-%d-%d");$z="-endian ";echo($m=$b&&$b<13)&&$c&&$c<32?big.$z:"",$m&&$a&&$a<32?little.$z:"",$a&&$a<13&&$b&&$b<32?middle.$z:"";
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a8fd337776b0823df4595de41d67a18c228945a7)

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 138 bytes

```
@echo off
set/ps=
call:l little %s:-= %
exit/b
:l
call:e big %4 %3
call:e middle %3 %2
:e
if %2 leq 31 if %3 leq 12 echo %1-endian
```

Vaguely based on @ovs's answer.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 131 bytes

```
[$a,$b,$c]=explode('-',$argn);foreach([[big,b,c],[little,b,a],[middle,a,b]]as[$t,$x,$y])echo$$x*$$y&&$$x<13&$$y<32?"$t-endian ":"";
```