# Character Cross

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

I was expecting to post something more complex as my first puzzle in PCG, but a particular, uh... [homework question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26623488/1461424) inspired me to post this. They want to:

> print the following pattern for any given word that contains **odd** number of letters:
>
> ```
> P           M
>   R       A   
>     O   R    
>       G       
>     O   R      
>   R       A   
> P           M
> ```
>
> [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

---

> Notice that letters are a knight's move apart in the pattern you need to print. So, every other column is empty. -- (Thanks [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for pointing this out.)

### Rules

1. Using C++ is prohibited. As I may link this question there.
2. You may use `stdout`, or any means of quickly outputting a string (e.g. `alert()` in JavaScript).
3. As always, shortest code wins.

Comment: This is in the related posts on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110

Comment: What do you mean by ODD?

Comment: @flawr I think it means odd, as in not an even number.

Comment: God I am stupid, I thought it was kind of an obscure computer scientist abbreviation=)

Comment: Is the shortest answer measured in bytes or characters?

Comment: @jpjacobs: Bytes, unless the question explicitly says otherwise.

Comment: Whole program or just a function? (real smart of me to answer first and make this question later...)

Comment: Notice that letters are a knight's move apart in the pattern you need to print. So, every other column is empty.

Comment: @krumia Congrats on posting a solid question as a first-time poster on PPCG! I hope you stick around.

Comment: @xnor That's not a knight's move, it's an [elephant's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiangqi#Elephant) move.

Comment: I might be the first person in history to migrate a question here (although with some modifications). :D

Comment: Any restrictions around leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: @streetster No, none. Have a go at it :)

Comment: @LilyChung If you select, there's an extra space. So it is indeed a horse move.

Comment: @PkmnQ Yep, I sure was wrong about that one back in 2014.

Comment: [Related golf problem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/86668/15940)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＼＼：⇵ｎ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNDJXVGRjNDJXVGRjFBJXUyMUY1JXVGRjRF,i=JTIyUFJPR1JBTSUyMg__,v=8)

Explanation:

```
\      create a diagonal of the input
 \     create an even steeper diagonal of that
  :⇵   reverse a copy of it vertically
    n  overlap the two
```

Answer (score 22):

### APL (<s>37</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 27)

```
↑{∊2↑¨⍵↑¨I}¨↓(+∨⌽)∘.=⍨⍳⍴I←⍞
```

It takes input from the keyboard, like so:

```
      ↑{∊2↑¨⍵↑¨I}¨↓(+∨⌽)∘.=⍨⍳⍴I←⍞
CODE-GOLF
C               F 
  O           L   
    D       O     
      E   G       
        -         
      E   G       
    D       O     
  O           L   
C               F
```

Comment: All of my upvotes belong to APL.

Answer (score 13):

## Python 2 - <s>94 90 89</s> 88

```
s=input()
L=len(s)
R=range(L)
for i in R:print" ".join([s[j]," "][j!=i!=L+~j]for j in R)
```

**Input:**

```
"CODE-GOLF"
```

**Output:**

```
C               F
  O           L  
    D       O    
      E   G      
        -        
      E   G      
    D       O    
  O           L  
C               F
```

Comment: I was just writing the same thing. My one improvement is `i in[j,L+~j]`.

Comment: @xnor: Found an even shorter condition. ;)

Comment: Clever. You can still do `L+~j` though.

Comment: @xnor: Ah, you're right. I always forget the `+~` trick...

Comment: Can you do `for i in R:print" ".join([s[j]," "][j!=i!=L+~j]for j in R)` to save a char? (I don't have access to Python 2 now to test.)

Comment: @xnor: That's exactly what I thought of in that second! :)

Answer (score 13):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22

```
Vzjdm?@zd}N,dt-lzd\ Uz
```

Test:

```
$ pyth -c 'Vzjdm?@zd}N,dt-lzd\ Uz' <<< "CODE-GOLF"
C               F
  O           L  
    D       O    
      E   G      
        -        
      E   G      
    D       O    
  O           L  
C               F
```

Explanation:

```
(Implicit)                  z = input()
(Implicit)                  d = ' '
Vz                          for N in range(len(z)):
  jd                            print(d.join(
    m                               map(lambda d:
     ?@zd                                        z[d] if
         }N                                      N in
           ,dt-lzd                                    (d,len(z)-d-1) else
      \                                          " ",
     Uz                                          range(len(z)))))
```

Comment: No bit complement in Pyth?

Comment: @xnor No, but it wouldn't help. Suppose `~` was bitwise not in Pyth. Then we could change `t-lzd` to `+lz~d` - still 5 characters.

Comment: `Vz` is a neat trick: I didn't know that `U<string>` gave `range(len(<string>))`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a nice feature. Works that way on lists too, but not tuples necessarily. EDIT: Oops, that's missing from the documentation. I'll add it. Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

### Python 3: 75 chars

```python
s=input()
i=n=len(s)
while i:i-=1;a=[" "]*n;a[i]=s[i];a[~i]=s[~i];print(*a)
```

For line `i`, we start with a list of spaces and set the entries `i` from the front and back to be equal to the letters of the input string. Then, we print the result.

Python strings are immutable, so `a` must be a list of characters instead. The list `a` must be initialized inside the loop or the modifications will carry over between loops. We use `print(*a)` to print each character in the list, space separated, which requires Python 3.

The output lines are symmetrical, so we can have `i` count down rather than up using a while loop.

```
>>> CODE-GOLF
C               F
  O           L  
    D       O    
      E   G      
        -        
      E   G      
    D       O    
  O           L  
C               F
```

It also works for an even number of letters.

```
>>> CODEGOLF
C             F
  O         L  
    D     O    
      E G      
      E G      
    D     O    
  O         L  
C             F
```

Comment: Converting this to Pyth, I get `VlzJ*]dlz=@JN@zN=@Jt_N@_zNjdJ` which is 29 bytes... I guess I'll have to try something else to beat APL. Also, +1 for proof that Python 3 can out-golf Python 2 (sometimes)

Comment: @fry Python 3 usually out-golfs 2 in my experience. Even if nothing changes anywhere else, most challenges give one input and expect one output, and `len("raw_input()") + len("print ") > len("input()") + len("print()")`.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail Well, the trouble with that is that `input()` [is also valid in python 2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40564/31625) (it just acts somewhat differently), so unless the input for the challenge is quite strict, python 2 will usually win out.

Comment: Wow, even with Python 2 and `print" ".join(a)` your code is shorter (82) than mine.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman See my answer - it's an adaptation of the other python answer, and it's much shorter than APL. Pyth really doesn't like assigning to indexes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
l_,S*:Sf{W):W2$tW~@tS}zN*
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

#### Example run

```
$ cjam <(echo 'l_,S*:Sf{W):W2$tW~@tS}zN*') <<< CROSS; echo
C       S 
  R   S   
    O     
  R   S   
C       S
```

As the example in the answer, each line has trailing whitespace.

#### How it works

```
                             " N := '\n'; R := []; S = ' '; W := -1 ";
l                            " Q := input()                         ";
 _,S*:S                      " S := len(Q) * S                      ";
       f{            }       " for each C in Q:                     ";
                             "   T := S                             ";
         W):W                "   W += 1                             ";
             2$t             "   T[W] := C                          ";
                W~@t         "   T[~W] := C                         ";
                             "   R += [T]                           ";
                    S        "   R += [S]                           ";
                      z      " R := zip(R)                          ";
                       N*    " R := N.join(R)                       ";
                             " print R                              ";
```

Comment: Sorry that this is basically a 'great answer!' comment, but I just had to say that it never, _ever_, would have occurred to me to build the box by columns instead of by rows.

Answer (score 5):

## Pure Bash, 94 bytes

```
l=${#1}
for((;t<l*l;t++));{
((x=t%l))||echo
((x-t/l&&x+t/l+1-l))&&printf \ ||printf ${1:x:1}
}
```

Comment: Too many `t%l` calculations. Save it on first use to a variable `((x=t%l))` then use the variable to reduce it to 94 characters.

Comment: Ah yes, I had done this for `x=t%l` and `y=t/l` and it was longer... didn't cross my mind just to use x only

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>99</s> <s>98</s> <s>93</s> 89 bytes

```
m=ifelse(diag(l<-length(w<-el(strsplit(scan(,''),'')))),w,' ')
write(pmax(m,m[,l:1]),1,l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcNLCoAgEADQq7SbGZgWbvucJFpYTiaMESrY7a0evNRanMMhmgVdsB516lUuX06sUy@KuaR8ayiYd3shA9D/w5WhAxprCkXwjvbByHFhHcxKbFipgd12J9Be)

Line 1 reads input string, splits it into characters, stores its length and creates a matrix with the word on its main diagonal – letters of the word are superposed on an identity matrix (and repeated by default to match its length) and only those matching 1's are retained, others being replaced by spaces.

Line 2 prints a matrix formed by elements of either the diagonal matrix or its horizontally mirrored version, whichever are greater.

*−2 + 1 = −1 byte thanks to [JayCe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80010/jayce)*

*−4 bytes thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

Comment: Sweet! And nice explanation.you can [save 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYuxDoQgEAV/xW6Xu7WgleNLjAWnK0fyNAZI@HxOi5liksm9w0PPWH/cPqOCS83lQqpc1nCyEJkHY9zh064oylsKkWGkCQ109xmTfWG8/baLb67lVJUPsQJ53k7hu25K/Q8)

Comment: looking at he other answers and the question - It seems like the matrix should be larger (extra space) - the output should not be a square matrix..

Comment: @JayCe Thanks for the 2 bytes! And thanks for the comment about formatting, you are probably right (although the rules could be more clear about this). Fortunately all it needed was putting a space into the separator while printing.

Comment: [89 bytes using `pmax`](https://tio.run/##FcNLCoAgEADQq7SbGZgWbvucJFpYTiaMESrY7a0evNRanMMhmgVdsB516lUuX06sUy@KuaR8ayiYd3shA9D/w5WhAxprCkXwjvbByHFhHcxKbFipgd12J9Be) and inlining some more assignments.

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! Sadly, still not enough to beat [J.Doe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81549/j-doe)'s [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176273/65510)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (E6) 101 <s>95 129 136</s>

**Edit** Wrong letter spacing. Fixed.
**Edit** Simpler and shorter using classic for loops
As a function, output via popup.

```javascript
F=a=>{
  for(l=a.length+1,i=s=o='';++i<l;s='\n')
    for(j=0;++j<l;)
      o+=s+((s=' ')+a)[j==i|i+j==l&&j]
  alert(o)
}
```

*Previous version* using .map

```javascript
F=a=>alert([...a].map((c,p)=>
  --q<p
  ?B(q)+a[q]+B(p-q-1)+c 
  :B(p)+c+(p-q?B(q-p-1)+a[q]:'')
,B=n=>' '.repeat(n),q=a.length).join('\n'))
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```javascript
F('Java-Script')
```

*Output*

```javascript
J                   t
  a               p  
    v           i    
      a       r      
        -   c        
          S          
        -   c        
      a       r      
    v           i    
  a               p  
J                   t
```

Comment: This doesn't have enough horizontal spacing - there should be columns of all spaces between each column with letters.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 64

```ruby
f=->w{x=w.size
x.times{|i|y=" "*x
y[i],y[~i]=w[i],w[~i]
puts y}}
```

### Explanation

- Input is taken as the argument to a lambda. It expects a `String`.
- In a loop that loops trough every character in the word (`n` in total):

  - Create a String consisting of `n` spaces.
  - Replace the `i`th and `n-i`th (`~i`, thanks xnor) space with the `i`th and `n-i`th character of the input.
  - Print the line

Comment: Congratulations on posting the 25,000th answer! :) (Actually, I'm not 100% sure, this is the one, due to caching. But it was the latest answer, when I first saw "25,000 answers" in the site stats.)

Comment: You can do `-i-1` as the bit complement `~i`.

Comment: That's very clever, thanks!

Comment: With this approach, it actually seems to be beneficial to use stdin instead of a lambda: `gets.size.times{|x|u=?\s*~/$/;u[x]=$_[x];u[~x]=$_[~x];puts u}` (assumes input is not terminated by a newline, e.g. `echo -n CODE-GOLF`). One can then make additional use of `.chars` to save another character: `x=0;gets.chars{|r|u=?\s*~/$/;u[x]=r;u[~x]=$_[-x+=1];puts u}`

Answer (score 4):

## Java - 168

A simple nested loop, there's nothing really special going on here.

```java
class C{public static void main(String[]a){int b=-1,c=a[0].length()-1,d;for(;b++<c;)for(d=-1;d++<c;)System.out.print((b==d|b==c-d?a[0].charAt(d):" ")+(c==d?"\n":""));}}
```

With line breaks:

```java
class C{
    public static void main(String[]a){
        int b=-1,c=a[0].length()-1,d;
        for(;b++<c;)
            for(d=-1;d++<c;)
                System.out.print(
                    (b==d|b==c-d?a[0].charAt(d):" ")+
                    (c==d?"\n":""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript 102 <strike>84 85</strike>

*Edit: Had to fix spacing. Not so small anymore.*

```
function p(s){for(i in s){o='';for(n in s)o+=(n==i?s[n]:n==s.length-1-i?s[n]:' ')+' ';console.log(o)}}

p('Thanks-Dennis')

T                       s
  h                   i
    a               n
      n           n
        k       e
          s   D
            -
          s   D
        k       e
      n           n
    a               n
  h                   i
T                       s
```

Comment: This does not have enough horizontal spacing.

Comment: Wow, shorter than [mine](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40590/32376) and not even using ES6. +1

Comment: Better, but the spacing is still wrong (look at the X). Also, unless the question says otherwise, you should write a program or a function. Snippets with hardcoded variables are generally frowned upon.

Comment: And can't you make it `function(s)` since you don't recurse?

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge-93, <s>68</s> 71

```
:~:84*-!#@#v_\:2*\4+p1+
::+\4+g:!| >$1+0:>p1-::
00+4\*2:\<>0p#:- ^#2g
```

You can test it [here](http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground). It'll come up with an input dialog box on each pass through `~`; enter your word one character at a time (it does say the input is 'klunky' after all), ending with a space.

It won't print to the console; this wouldn't be Befunge without a hint of self-modification, after all! Instead it will modify its own grid to display the message. After it's done, the grid will look something like this:

```
 ~:84*-!#@#v_\:2*\4+p1+
::+\4+g:!| >$1+0:>p1-::
00+4\*2:\<>0p#:- ^#2g

c               f      
  o           l        
    d       o          
      e   g            
        -              
      e   g            
    d       o          
  o           l        
c               f
```

(Note the noble sacrifice of the cell at (0,0), after we know the pointer won't go there anymore, for the purpose of storing a piece of data.)

It also works with inputs of even length. Note that, since Befunge-93 is limited to an 80x25 grid, the input size is limited to 21 characters if you run it in a Befunge-93 interpreter. Running it as Befunge-98 should remove this limit.

*Edit* - Now it works more along the lines of the intended output, at the expense of only three characters of length.

Comment: Note that the letters are separated with a blank column. Letters are relatively in L shape.

Comment: Drats! That complicated things rather significantly. I think I can salvage this, but it'll add to the ending size... oh well.

Answer (score 3):

### CJam, <s>38</s> <s>36</s> <s>35</s> <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
l:I,,_f{f{_2$=@2$+I,(=|\I=S?S}N}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/) This reads the input word from STDIN. It also works for an even number of characters. This prints a trailing column of spaces, but I don't see anything in the rules against that.

Explanation

```
l:I,,_f{f{_2$=@2$+I,(=|\I=S?S}N}
l:I                              "Read input and store it in I.";
   ,                             "Get string length.";
    ,_                           "Turn into range and duplicate.";
      f{                       } "Map block onto first range, with second range on the stack.";
        f{                   }   "Map block onto second range, with first iterator in stack.
                                  Each invocation of this block will start with grid coordinates
                                  y and x on the stack (x on top).";
          _2$=                   "Duplicate x, duplicate y, check for equality.";
              @2$+               "Pull up y, duplucate x, add,";
                  I,(=           "Check if that's one less than the string length.";
                      |          "Bitwise or between conditions.";
                       \         "Swap condition and x.";
                        I=       "Take x'th character from the string.";
                          S?     "Push a space and select character depending on condition.";
                            S    "Push another space.";
                              N  "Push a line feed.";
```

The contents of the stack are printed automatically at the end of the program.

Comment: My dear CJam, you've just got beaten by APL. ^_^

Comment: @vaxquis I was surprised I was able to beat it twice in the first place. This problem seems much more suited to APL and co than to stack-based languages.

Comment: well, at least it's easier to write `l:I,,_f{f{_2$=@2$+I,(=|\I=S?S}N}` on a napkin than `↑{∊2↑¨⍵↑¨I}¨↓(+∨⌽)∘.=⍨⍳⍴I←⍞` ... *chuckle*

Comment: Well, someone else managed to beat me using CJam, and I can't make my program any shorter, so CJam did eventually beat me. (But Pyth gets the crown.) (That said, @vaxquis, APL is far easier to read than most of the other languages used on here, certainly once you know the 60 or so characters, and *certainly* when compared to Pyth or CJam or even J.)

Answer (score 3):

## C, 105

two slightly different ways of doing it.

```
c,i,j;main(int l,char**v){for(l=strlen(v[1]);j-l;)putchar((c=v[1][i++])?i-1-j&&l-i-j?32:c:(i=0,j++,10));}

i,j;main(int l,char**v){for(l=strlen(v[1]);j-l;i++)putchar((l-i)?i-j&&l-i-j-1?32:v[1][i]:(i=-1,j++,10));}
```

If you want to add extra spaces, replace `putchar(` with `printf(" %c",` for an extra 5 characters.

Answer (score 3):

### J - <strike>36</strike> 30 bytes:

*Edit:* 6 characters shorter, credits go to  [@algorithmshark](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5138/algorithmshark) .

```
(1j1#"1' '&,({~](*>.*&|.)=)#\)
```

eg:

```
   (1j1#"1' '&,({~](*>.*&|.)=)#\) 'Code-Golf'
C               f
  o           l  
    d       o    
      e   G      
        -        
      e   G      
    d       o    
  o           l  
C               f
```

Bonus: works with even length strings too:

```
   (1j1#"1' '&,({~](*>.*&|.)=)#\) 'CodeGolf'
C             f
  o         l  
    d     o    
      e G      
      e G      
    d     o    
  o         l  
C             f
```

Answer (score 3):

## Prolog - 240 bytes

```
:-initialization m.
+[]. +[H|T]:-(H=' ';!),+T.
+[H|T]+I+X:-0=:=I,X=H;+T+(I-1)+X.
+L+I+C+S:-L=:=I;S=[D|E],+C+I+B,+C+(L-I-1)+B,+B+2*I+D,+L+(I+1)+C+E,+B,writef('%s\n',[B]).
-X:-get_char(C),(C='\n',X=[];X=[C|Y],-Y).
m:- -X,length(X,L),+L+0+_+X.
```

Invocation:

```
$ echo "Code-Golf" | swipl -qf c.pl
C               f
  o           l
    d       o
      e   G
        -
      e   G
    d       o
  o           l
C               f
```

Readable:

```
:- initialization(main).

vars_to_spaces([]).
vars_to_spaces([' '|T]) :- vars_to_spaces(T).
vars_to_spaces([_|T]) :- vars_to_spaces(T).

get_index([Head|_], Index, Result) :-
    0 =:= Index,
    Result = Head.
get_index([_|Tail], Index, Result) :-
    get_index(Tail, Index-1, Result).

print_loop(Length, Index, Board, String) :-
    Length =:= Index;
    String = [FirstChar|RestString],
    get_index(Board, Index, Line),
    get_index(Board, Length-Index-1, Line),
    get_index(Line, 2*Index, FirstChar),
    print_loop(Length, Index+1, Board, RestString),
    vars_to_spaces(Line),
    writef('%s\n', [Line]).

get_line(Line) :-
    get_char(C),
    (   C = '\n', Line = [];
        Line = [C|More], get_line(More)).

main :-
    get_line(String),
    length(String, Length),
    print_loop(Length, 0, _, String).
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
LḶḤ⁶ẋ;"µ»ṚY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//TOG4tuG4pOKBtuG6izsiwrXCu@G5mln///9QUk9HUkFN)

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 78 bytes

+8 bytes thanks @[streetster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69200/streetster)

```
param($s)$s|% t*y|%{$r=,' '*$s.length;$r[+$i++]=$_;$r[-$i]=$s[-$i];$r-join' '}
```

Explaned test script:

```
$f = {

param($s)               # declare a parameter $s stores a word
$s|% t*y|%{             # split $s into chars https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168174/80745
    $r=,' '*$s.length   # create an array of spaces with length equal length of the word
    $r[$i++]=$_         # set first char
    $r[-$i]=$s[-$i]     # set last char
    $r-join' '          # join the array to string
}

}

&$f PROGRAM
''
&$f sword
''
&$f uhm
''
&$f o
''
&$f codegolf  # It works with word that contains even number of letters
```

## Powershell, 70 bytes (if a word can be represented by an array of chars)

+8 bytes thanks @[streetster](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69200/streetster)

```
($s=$args)|%{$r=,' '*$s.count;$r[+$i++]=$_;$r[-$i]=$s[-$i];$r-join' '}
```

Test script:

```
$f = {

($s=$args)|%{$r=,' '*$s.count;$r[+$i++]=$_;$r[-$i]=$s[-$i];$r-join' '}

}

&$f P R O G R A M
''
&$f s w o r d
''
&$f u h m
''
&$f o
''
&$f c o d e g o l f  # It works with word that contains even number of letters
```

Output for both cases:

```
P           M
  R       A
    O   R
      G
    O   R
  R       A
P           M

s       d
  w   r
    o
  w   r
s       d

u   m
  h
u   m

o

c             f
  o         l
    d     o
      e g
      e g
    d     o
  o         l
c             f
```

Comment: Since you can take input as a `char`-array ([Meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2216/42963)), that can save some bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure that the `word` in the rule `print the following pattern for any given word that contains odd number of letters` means `an array of chars` in a Powershell :) But I've updated post

Comment: Aren't you crossing the wrong way?

Comment: @streetster, you are best! I've updated the post.

Comment: Oof, +8 bytes - sorry!

Comment: But now the crossing is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

### C# (<s>214</s> 212)

(Certainly badly) Golfed version:

```
using System;class A{static void Main(){char[]a,w=Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();int l=w.Length,i=0;for(;i<l;i++){a=new string(' ',2*l-1).ToCharArray();a[2*i]=w[i];a[2*l-2*i-2]=w[l-i-1];Console.WriteLine(a);}}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
using System;

class A
{
  static void Main()
  {
    char[] a, w = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
    int l = w.Length, i = 0;
    for (; i < l; i++)
    {
      a = new string(' ', 2 * l - 1).ToCharArray();
      a[2 * i] = w[i];
      a[2 * l - 2 * i - 2] = w[l - i - 1];
      Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
  }
}
```

Any hints, tips, tricks or remarks are very welcome, as this is my first attempt at CodeGolf. I just wanted to try it, even though I know my C# byte length won't even come close to double the best solutions ;)

And how do you guys count your bytes? I just posted the above into a Quick Watch window and did `.Length`. I could write a small program to count bytes for me, but I bet there is an easier way that I don't yet know.

Comment: You can save two bytes by removing the spaces in `for(;i < l;i++)`.

Comment: Also, I use [this](http://www.charactercountonline.com) for my byte counting.

Comment: @BetaDecay Ah great, I must have overlooked those. And thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) - <s>185</s> <s>177</s> <s>175</s> 170 bytes

```
f=n=>{return s='  ',r='repeat',n=[...n],l=n.length,j=l/2-.5,[...h=n.slice(0,j).map((c,i)=>s[r](i)+c+s[r](l-2-(i*2))+' '+n[l-i-1]),s[r](j)+n[j],...h.reverse()].join('\n')}
```

Put this in the Firefox console and run as `f('PROGRAM')`:

```
P           M
  R       A
    O   R
      G
    O   R
  R       A
P           M
```

`f("CODE-GOLF")`:

```
C               F
  O           L
    D       O
      E   G
        -
      E   G
    D       O
  O           L
C               F
```

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40594/26974

Comment: I saw that one too.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 149 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode@Flatten[Append[Riffle[#,32],10]&/@MapThread[Max,{#,Reverse@#,ConstantArray[32,Dimensions@#]},2]&@DiagonalMatrix@ToCharacterCode@#]&
```

Input passed as parameter to the function; function returns the output string. There is a trailing newline at the end of the output.

Explanation: We create a diagonal matrix with the string, then we create a copy of it vertically flipped using `Reverse@#` to reverse the rows. Then we have a third matrix of the same dimensions containing only 32 (ascii space). We use `MapThread` to take the element-wise max of these 3 matrices. Finally, we `Riffle` spaces into each row, `Append` a newline at the end, and `Flatten` the result.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl - 90

It might be possible to squeeze some more characters out of this:

```
($j=$i++%8)==7?++$k&&print"\n":print$j+1==$k||7-$j==$k?"$_ ":"  "for split//,($_ x y///c)
```

`89` + `1` for `-n`.

Run with:

```
echo "program" | perl -nE'($j=$i++%8)==7?++$k&&print"\n":print$j+1==$k||7-$j==$k?"$_ ":"  "for split//,($_ x y///c)'
```

Output:

```
p           m
  r       a
    o   r
      g
    o   r
  r       a
p           m
```

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell <s>118</s> <s>102</s> 97

```
($x=[char[]]"$args")|%{$i++;$y=[char[]]" "*$x.Count;$y[$i-1]=$x[$i-1];$y[-$i]=$x[-$i];$y-join' '}
```

Outputs:

```
PS C:\PowerShell> .\cross.ps1 SWORD
S       D
  W   R
    O
  W   R
S       D
```

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL: 180

Taking the input from variable @i

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)=REPLICATE('  ',LEN(@i)),@ INT=1a:PRINT STUFF(STUFF(@s,@*2-1,1,SUBSTRING(@i,@,1)),LEN(@i)*2-(@*2)+1,1,SUBSTRING(@i,LEN(@i)-@+1,1))SET @+=1IF @<=LEN(@i)GOTO A
```

This stuffs single characters in/decrementing from the start and end into a string of spaces.

Test Result

```
DECLARE @i VARCHAR(MAX)='Super Large'
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)=REPLICATE('  ',LEN(@i)),@ INT=1a:PRINT STUFF(STUFF(@s,@*2-1,1,SUBSTRING(@i,@,1)),LEN(@i)*2-(@*2)+1,1,SUBSTRING(@i,LEN(@i)-@+1,1))SET @+=1IF @<=LEN(@i)GOTO A
S                   e 
  u               g   
    p           r     
      e       a       
        r   L         

        r   L         
      e       a       
    p           r     
  u               g   
S                   e
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 81 bytes

```javascript
f=s=>[...s].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((c,j)=>j==i|j==s.length+~i?c:' ').join` `).join`
`
```

**EDIT**: -1 Thanks Joe King. I didn't see the TIO gives preformatted direct paste for CG.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdBCsIwEEDRvaco3TTBOAdQph5ExAxpWhNipmSK3RSvHgu6@fwX6U3iSpiXU@bB1zqiYH8DALnDi2alHiYY0tjTj87EHRExbHsEks/T8jx@wtWdu6bTEDlk29j/HGx1nIWTh8STGlW7chlcYZFW60v9Ag)

Comment: btw, the excess code to execute the code in TIO can go in the program footer. This helps determine the correct byte count and use the automated PPCG answer format more smoothly. e.g. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcdBCsIwEEDRvaco3TSBZMCtMvUgImZI05oQMyVTdOPdY0E3n/8SvUh8jetmC0@htRkFxysAyA2etCp1N9GQxpF@9CbtSIjxs0cgh7JsDxvt8eJPQzdoSByL69x/Dq55LsI5QOZFzap/c518ZZFe63P7Ag "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: `-i-1` can be `+~i`

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
â┤▼iS╙£≥»u5V╓
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=83b41f6953d39cf2af753556d6&i=%22PROGRAM%22&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
{       begin block for mapping characters of input
  ]i^)  left-pad each character to length (i+1) where i is the index
m       map using block
r       reverse the array; this produces the southwest-northeast diagonal
m       map using the rest of the program, implicitly output result
  i     iteration index
  xi@   get the i'th character of the original input, where i is the iteration
  &     assign element to array at index
  0\    join with spaces
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B+++++%09begin+block+for+mapping+characters+of+input%0A++]i%5E%29%09left-pad+each+character+to+length+%28i%2B1%29+where+i+is+the+index%0Am+++++%09map+using+block%0Ar+++++%09reverse+the+array%3B+this+produces+the+southwest-northeast+diagonal%0Am+++++%09map+using+the+rest+of+the+program,+implicitly+output+result%0A++i+++%09iteration+index%0A++xi%40+%09get+the+i%27th+character+of+the+original+input,+where+i+is+the+iteration%0A++%26+++%09assign+element+to+array+at+index%0A++0%5C++%09join+with+spaces&i=%22PROGRAM%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 88 bytes

```r
n=ncol(m<-diag(u<-utf8ToInt(scan(,""))-32));diag(m[,n:1])=u;write(intToUtf8(m+32,T),1,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P882Lzk/RyPXRjclMzFdo9RGt7QkzSIk3zOvRKM4OTFPQ0dJSVNT19hIU9MarCI3WifPyjBW07bUurwosyRVIzOvJCQ/FKhJI1fb2EgnRFPHUCdP839AkL97kKPvfwA)

Comment: Nice! Like me, you can [save 2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P882Lzk/RyPXRjclMzFdo9RGt7QkzSIk3zOvRKM4OTFPQ0dJSVNT19hIU9O6vCizJFUjM68kJD8UqEijIDexQiNXJzdaJ8/KMFZT29hIJ0RTx1AnT/N/QJC/e5Cj738A) by using `pmax` (originally [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)'s suggestion).

Comment: This won't work with length 1 input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＼：↶ｎ ＊
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjNDJXVGRjFBJXUyMUI2JXVGRjRFJTIwJXVGRjBB,i=UFJPR1JBTQ__,v=8)

## Explanation

```
＼       Create a diagonal with the input
 ：      Duplicate the diagonal
  ↶     Rotate left
    ｎ   Simple overlap 
      ＊ Insert spaces on every line
```

Comment: There is already a [5-byte Canvas answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/176280/52210), but nice approach regardless! :)

Comment: I see, the built-in is `ｎ`...

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh, <s>90</s> 82 bytes

Kudos to @pxeger for saving 8 bytes.

```bash
for i ({1..$#1})(for z (${(s::)1}){((i==++j||j+i==$#1+1))||z=\ 
printf $z\ }
echo)
```

[Attempt this Online](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3g9LyixQyFTSqDfX0VJQNazU1QAJVChoq1RrFVlaaQJFqDY1MW1tt7ayamixtIAuoTNtQU7Ompso2RoGroCgzryRNQaUqRqGWKzU5I18TYjLUgvXRSpHOHkH-vv7B_r6uSrFQYQA)   <sub><s>[90 bytes](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9Py2/SCFTQaPaUE9PRdmwVrMaJJCFLKChkWlrm1VTk6UNpIFC2oaammpqVbYq1YbRWbG1NTVVtjEKXAVFmXklaQoqVTEKtVypyRn5tf9rudIUIp09gvx9/YP9fV3/AwA)</s></sub>

Comment: [82 bytes with a bit of a rejig of the loops](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3g9LyixQyFTSqDfX0VJQNazU1QAJVChoq1RrFVlaaQJFqDY1MW1tt7ayamixtIAuoTNtQU7Ompso2RoGroCgzryRNQaUqRqGWKzU5I18TYjLUgvXRSpHOHkH-vv7B_r6uSrFQYQA)

Comment: Nice, I knew it needed more optimisation!

Answer (score 1):

### C# 208

```
static void Main()
{
string s=Console.ReadLine(),t="";
int n=s.Length;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
if(i==j)t+=s[i];
else if(i==n-j-1)t+=s[n-i-1];
t+=" ";
}
t+="\n";
}
Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Comment: Save 11 precious characters with `t+=i==j?s[i]:i==n-j-1?s[n-i-1]:"";`.

Comment: Can you remove those newlines?

Answer (score 1):

No matter how long, there's always gotta be an answer in...

## Java - <s>289</s> 234 bytes

```
public static void main(String[]a){int l=a.length-1,i=0,j;for(;i<=l;i++){for(j=0;j<=l;j++){if(j==i)System.out.print(a[i]);else if(i==l-j)System.out.print(a[j]);else System.out.print(" ");System.out.print(" ");}System.out.println();}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
    class A {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int l = a.length - 1, i = 0, j;
        for (; i <= l; i++) {
            for (j=0; j <= l;j++) {
                if (j == i)
                    System.out.print(a[i]);
                else if (i == l-j)
                    System.out.print(a[j]);
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
                System.out.print(" ");
                }            
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output, lousily done, is:

```
P           M 
  R       A   
    O   R     
      G       
    O   R     
  R       A   
P           M
```

<s>Added the `import java.util.Scanner` inside the code because I never remember if the imports count towards the byte count...</s> Damn, I really suck at this.

Comment: Imports do count. This is partly because of Python's import-and-alias syntax: `from math import floor as f` which is a bit cheaty

Comment: You should be able to save a bunch of characters by combining all the `System.out.print` calls into one, using a couple of ternary operators.

Comment: @DLosc Could you give me a few examples?

Comment: Yes, actually [Geobits' answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40630/16766) is a perfect example--see the contents of the `System.out.print` call at the end.

Comment: See, replies like Geobits' make me feel like I know so little of Java. I was thinking about creating an empty `String` and appending to it the spaces and characters, using the `System.out.println` to output it only at the end. Oh well...

Comment: @RodolfoDias Don't feel that way. My first few golfs in Java were *terrible*, and I can still normally shave a decent chunk off my "first revisions" if I look hard enough ;)

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript 46 ([DEMO](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydQUk9HUkFNJwoKOncsOmwse2wsey5bLmwoXC1dMiQ%2FKSF3QFs9MzJdPX0lXDsnJysnICcqfSVuKg%3D%3D&run=true))

```rb
:w,:l,{l,{.[.l(\-]2$?)!w@[=32]=}%\;''+' '*}%n*
```

Answer (score 1):

## C# (192 / 170)

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){var s=Console.ReadLine();int x,y,l=s.Length;for(x=0;x<l;x++){for(y=0;y<l;y++)Console.Write(x==y||l-x==y+1?s.Substring(x,1):" ");Console.Write("\n");};}}
```

Or, as "Main() only":

```
static void Main(){var s=Console.ReadLine();int x,y,l=s.Length;for(x=0;x<l;x++){for(y=0;y<l;y++)Console.Write(x==y||l-x==y+1?s.Substring(x,1):" ");Console.Write("\n");};}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Tutorial), <s>9</s> <s>7</s> <s>17</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal/wiki/Code-page)

```
↘Ｓ⟲ＯＯＬθＵＥ¹
```

+10 bytes because I missed the requirement of space-columns.
-7 bytes thanks to *@ASCII-only*.

[Try it online (verbose)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88LygzPaNER8Ezr6C0JLgEKJ6uoalpzRWUX5JYkupfllqUk1gApTR8UvPSSzI0CkEKXCtKUvNSNAw1rYHGBfm7Bzn6/tctywEA) or [try it only (pure)](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R24z3ezY/mr/p/Z71YLTm3I73e7a@37P00M7//wOC/N2DHH0B).

Challenges like this is why Charcoal was made.

**Explanation:**

Print the input-string in a down-right direction:

```
Print(:DownRight, InputString());
↘Ｓ
```

Rotate it 90 degree counterclockwise, and shift it up the length of the input-string amount of times with overlap:

```
RotateOverlapOverlap(Length(q));
⟲ＯＯＬθ
```

Put a space gap of size 1 between every column:

```
Extend(1);
ＵＥ¹
```

Comment: It's not exactly diagonal. There should be an empty column between characters.

Comment: @Krumia Should be fixed now.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen [10](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMPKJb88LygzPaNER8Ezr6C0JLgEKJ6uoalpzRWUX5JYkupfllqUk1gApTR8UvPSSzI0CkEKXCtKUvNSNAw1rYHGBfm7Bzn6/tctywEA)

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks! Didn't knew about `Extend`, but it's just what was necessary here.

Comment: XD > try it only

Comment: @ASCII-only Ah oops, lol.. I'll just leave that in. ;p

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, 91 bytes

```
INPUT w$
l=LEN(w$)
FOR i=1TO l
c$=MID$(w$,i,1)
LOCATE i+1,i*2
?c$
LOCATE l-i+2,i*2
?c$
NEXT
```

Loops through the input word and uses the `LOCATE` statement to place each letter (twice) on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 31 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$a||a:(2*#x)$(-1-2*!#x)$,:'x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZJbGmJtFKw0hLuUJTRUPXUNdISxHE1LFSr7BSSs5PSdVNz89JU/r/HwA)

**Explanation:**

Generate the diagonal, and or with the reverse of the diagonal

```
`c$a||a:(2*#x)$(-1-2*!#x)$,:'x: / the solution
                             x: / save input as x
                          ,:'   / enlist (,:) each-both (')
                         $      / pad (negative is right-pad)
               (        )       / do this together
                      #x        / count (#) length of x
                     !          / range (!) 0..this count
                   2*           / double it
                -1-             / subtract from -1
              $                 / pad
        (    )                  / do this together
           #x                   / count (#) length of x
         2*                     / multiply by 2
      a:                        / save as a
     |                          / reverse (|) it
   a|                           / or (|) with a
`c$                             / cast to characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), 26 bytes

**Solution:**

```
a||a:(2*#x)$(-1-2*!#x)$$x:
```

**Explanation:**

Similar to my [oK](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170826/69200) answer but a little shorter:

```
a||a:(2*#x)$(-1-2*!#x)$$x: / the solution
                        x: / save input as x
                       $   / string ($) breaks into char lists
                      $    / cast ($)
            (        )     / do this together
                   #x      / count (#) length of x
                  !        / range (!) 0..this count
                2*         / double it
             -1-           / subtract from -1
           $               / pad
     (    )                / do this together
        #x                 / count (#) length of x
      2*                   / multiply by 2
   a:                      / save as a
  |                        / reverse (|) it
a|                         / or (|) with a
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 81 bytes

```php
for($k=strlen($s=$argn);$k;$t[2*$i]=$s[$i++],$t[2*--$k]=$s[$k],print"$t
")$t=" ";
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5dbe40448deed5c20e4723324dbe02d3d7eb2f5).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 176 bytes

```python
w=input();l=len(w);d=l//2;n=' ';x=range(d)
for i in x:print(n*i*2+w[i],n*(l+2-i*4),w[-1*i-1])
print(n*(l-1)+w[d])
for i in x:print(n*(l-i*2-3)+w[-1*(d+i+2)],n*(i*4+1),w[d+i+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcxBDoMgEIXhvadg5wASA3ZVwkmMCxOsnYSOhGiwp6fYpLtuZ/73xff@3GgoJTukeOzAbXBhIcjcehf63lhyLWvt6dJM6wKeN48tMWRI7LzHhLQDCRRG5hGnjgQEaRSKG@/yqLRApSfe/DoISvNa@ukvU99VUsOV1C14idLwr1pFqS/zulWylJi2Nc2vDw)

This is super stupid, any improvements that you notice are welcome

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 75 bytes

```
Input Str1
length(Str1→L
For(I,1,L
" 
For(J,1,L
If max(J={I,1-I+L:Then
Ans+sub(Str1,J,1)+" 
Else
Ans+"  
End
End
Disp Ans
End
```

There is 1 space at the end of lines 4 and 7, and there are 2 spaces at the end of line 9. Outputs a leading space at the beginning of each line.

---

Alternatively, a larger but faster method (100 bytes):

```
Input Str1
length(Str1→L
" 
For(I,1,L
Ans+"  →Str2
End
For(I,1,L
min(I,1-I+L→K
2(max(L,2)-Ans
Disp sub(Str2+sub(Str1,K,1)+Str2,Ans+4,Ans)+sub(Str1,L-K+1,1
End
```

There is 1 space at the end of line 3. Outputs two leading spaces if the input has a length of 1.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ṪṭaɗƤ⁶»Ṛ$G
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9qZWxsef//4bmq4bmtYcmXxqTigbbCu@G5miRH////UFJPR1JBTQ)

Erik's existing answer ties with minor modifications to also use `G`: `LḶ⁶ẋ;"µ»ṚG`.

```
    Ƥ         For each prefix of the input,
Ṫ             remove the last element
 ṭ            and append it back onto
  aɗ ⁶        the remaining elements replaced with spaces.
      »       Take the maximum of each element of that and
       Ṛ$     its reverse.
         G    Grid format: join each row on spaces then join the rows on newlines.
```

Answer (score -2):

## C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char a[] = {'P','R','O','G','R','A','M'};
    int length = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
    int l = length - 1, i, j;
    for (i=0; i <= l; i++) {
        for (j=0; j <= l;j++) {
            if (j == i)
                std::cout<<a[i];
            else if (i == l-j)
                std::cout<<a[j];
            else
                std::cout<<"s";
        }            
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is [tag:code-golf] which means that the goal is to solve the problem in as few bytes as code as possible. [As per our help centre](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) every answer should make a reasonable stab at the given winning criterion (within the limits of their language), which would mean at least removing unnecessary whitespace and using single-character variable names. You can always include a readable/"ungolfed" version in addition to the competitive one. Once you've done this, please also include the byte count of your code in the header.

Comment: And anyways, per the rules, using C++ is prohibited.