# Print alphabet without using strings

Tags: code-golf

The challenge: Write a script to print the alphabet, but you can't use any ASCII strings in your program. Unicode escape characters are allowed (if thats what you call them).

External libraries are allowed, as long as a link to the documentation is provided, and an online example if possible.

As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the answer with the shortest byte count will win!

Comment: @Adnan Updated the question with more information - IMO, it is not a duplicate

Comment: Another [do X without Y challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/86668/48934)... I mean [do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8079/48934) challenge.

Comment: It's kind of a tricky case, since almost all answers in that challenge also don't use strings. That means that most of the answers can be reused for this challenge.

Comment: By the way, you can always use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/34388) for writing challenges before posting them on the main site :). It's very useful for writing challenges, since you get feedback and find out whether it has been done before or not.

Comment: @Adnan Ah thank you, wasn't aware about that - ill be sure to use it for future questions and ill look at it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Silicon](http://github.com/m654z/Silicon), 1 byte

```
A
```

`A` is preinitialized to the alphabet. Output is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

### [Neoscript](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/neoscript), 27 bytes

```
{|65:[]:90:map(chr):fuse()}
```

Lambda returning the alphabet.