# Very Simple Triangles

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Write a program or function that takes in a positive integer (via stdin, command line, or function arg) and prints or returns a string of that many of these small triangles tiled together, alternating which way they point:

```
 /\
/__\
```

This sole triangle is the output if the input is `1`.

If the input is `2`, the output is

```
  ____
 /\  /
/__\/
```

If the input is `3`, the output is

```
  ____
 /\  /\
/__\/__\
```

If the input is `4`, the output is

```
  ________
 /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/
```

And so on. Your program must support inputs up to 2<sup>16</sup> - 1 = 65535.

**Details**

- The leftmost triangle always points upwards.
- There may be trailing spaces but there may not be unnecessary leading spaces.
- There may be an optional trailing newline.
- Note that for `1` the output is two lines long but otherwise it's three. This is required.
- The shortest submission [in bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter) wins.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>44</s> 42

```
ItQpdd*\_*4/Q2)jbms<*dQhQ,c" /\ "2,\/"__\\
```

The first line:

```
ItQpdd*\_*4/Q2)
ItQ           )    If the input is not 1
   pdd             Print two spaces
      *\_*4/Q2     Then groups of 4 underscores, repeated input/2 times.
```

The other two lines are generated by noticing that the second line consists of `" /"` and `"\ "` alternating input + 1 times, and the third line consists of `"/"` and `"__\"` alternated in the same fashion.

Comment: striked out 44 is still normal 44 :(

Comment: **42**. *Of course!*

Comment: 42 ?  We have a winner!! O.o lol

Comment: @Optimizer: I find it endlessly amusing that your sadness over the appearance of 44 has received more votes than the question _or_ this answer.

Comment: 3 bytes - doubling with `y` is the same as `*4/2`

Comment: @Maltysen `*4/1 2 = 0`, `y1 = 2`. `/` is floored, which is necessary behavior.

Comment: Just got 10 answers deep in the crossed out 44 chain

Comment: @AlexA. I find it endlessly amusing that your amusement over Optimizer's sadness over the appearance of 44 has received more votes than the question or this answer.

Comment: @isaacg Unfortunately false now

Comment: @Quintec Fortunately true again!

Answer (score 24):

## SQL, <s>182</s> <s>175</s> <s>173</s> 187 bytes

Not that this'll ever be the shortest, but it's still amusing to try to minimize sql ;) lol
I did this in Oracle 11, however, these should be basic SQL.
[edit] as pointed out, I didn't apply the when input = 1 rule - only show 2 lines. can't think of a better way to do it, however, I did save a couple bytes by modifying the v logic ;) adding 2 ahead of time saves a couple bytes by not having to repeat it later [/edit]

```sql
select decode(&i,1,'',rpad('  ',v,'____')||z)||rpad(' /',v,'\  /')||decode(y,1,'\')||z||rpad('/',v-1,'__\/')||decode(y,1,'__\')from(select 2+floor(&i/2)*4v,mod(&i,2)y,chr(10)z from dual);
```

[edit1] removed some unnecessary spaces[/edit1]
[edit2] changed &&i to just &i.  It cuts down 2 chars, but forces user to input the # of triangles twice ... :P I realized my "good coding habits" using &&i were costing be 2 bytes!! The horror!! [/edit2]

**Explanation**
(note: I use &&1 in this explanation so it only prompts once, the &1 above saves code space, but prompts multiple times ;) )

```sql
 select  -- line 1
     decode(&&1,1,'',   -- don't need line 1 if input is 1
     rpad('  ',v,'____') || z ) || -- every pair of triangles
     -- line 2
     rpad(' /',v,'\  /') ||  -- every pair of triangles
          decode(y,1,'\') || z || -- add the final triangle, input: 1,3,5 etc.
     -- line 3
     rpad('/',v-1,'__\/') ||  -- every pair of triangles
          decode(y,1,'__\')   -- add the final triangle, input: 1,3,5 etc.
from (select 2+floor(&&i/2)*4 v,   -- common multiplier. 4 extra chars for every triangle pair
             mod(&&i,2) y,  -- Flag for the final triangle (odd inputs, 1,3,5, etc)
             chr(10) z  -- CR, here to save space.
        from dual);
```

**Output**

```sql
  SQL> accept i
  1
  SQL> /

   /\
  /__\


  SQL> accept i
  2
  SQL> /

    ____
   /\  /
  /__\/


  SQL> accept i
  3
  SQL> /

    ____
   /\  /\
  /__\/__\


  SQL> accept i
  12
  SQL> /

    ________________________
   /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
  /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/


  SQL>
```

Comment: Would it work to remove the space after `from`? If so that'll save you a byte.

Comment: oh good lord .. that's nuts . just tried it .. and then "went to town" stripping out what spaces I could ... O.o  This sucker's unreadable now .. but it works still ;) lol  (I can NOT believe the aliases still work like that .. O.o  hehe )

Comment: I'm sooo confused on the upvotes! O.o It's nowhere near the smallest size .. yet .. upvotes!  O.o  wow.

Comment: Upvotes typically denote that people like your submission because it's creative, the language used is uncommon, or any number of reasons. In my experience it's uncommon for the shortest code golf answer to also be the highest voted. So while this may not be the shortest answer, the community has deemed it a good one. :)

Comment: @Alex .. cool, gravy :)  (i'm gonna have to try this in Excel next ... lol )

Comment: Line 1 should probably be `decode(&&i,1,'',rpad('  ',2+v,'____') || z) ||`.

Comment: @freekvd: why? that'll make it longer, and as it is, the rpad will chunk it back appropriately. It needs 2 leading spaces .. always, for any "i" > 0. (and for i = 1, the spaces are "visible", so doesn't matter .. ;) )

Comment: Because for i=1 it has to be 2 lines long instead of 3. It says so in the challenge details.

Comment: add .. didn't notice that before .. thx ... let me rethink that. :)

Comment: @freekvd: Thx for catching that - fixed (I hope) .. :)

Answer (score 11):

## Python 2, <s>89</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> <s>85</s> 83 named / 81 unnamed

```py
f=lambda n:1%n*("  "+n/2*4*"_"+"\n")+(" /\ "*n)[:2+2*n]+"\n"+("/__\\"*n)[:n-~n+n%2]
```

*(Thanks to @orlp for a byte, and @xnor for another three)*

This is a function which takes in an int `n` and returns the triangles as a string using the row-by-row approach.

e.g. `print f(10)` gives

```
  ____________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
```

For the first row, instead of `(n>1)*` we use `1%n*`, since `1%n` is 0 if `n == 1` and 1 if `n > 1`.

Comment: You can shave off a character, turning `" /\\ "` into `" /\ "`.

Comment: Doesn't this lambda work in Python 3 also?

Comment: @mbomb007 There's a floor division in there

Comment: @orlp Allow me now, to add further confusion, but deleting my comment ;)

Comment: I'm suspicious of the `"\n".join()` for 3 items, even if the list is used to conditionally remove the first element. Perhaps something like `b*(x+"\n")+y+"\n"+z` is shorter?

Comment: Ah, the good old `1%n`. For the `2*n-~(n%2)`, I think it can be `n-~n+n%2`.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 101 <s>109</s>

Way too long

```js
f=(n,z=a=>a.repeat(n/2))=>(n>1?'  '+z('____')+'\n ':' ')+z('/\\  ',w=' /'[++n&1]+'\n')+w+z('/__\\')+w
```

**Explanation**

Using fat arrow for function definition. Moreover no `{}` block: the function body is a single expression that is the return value. `f=(a,b,c)=>expr` is equivalent to

```
function f(a,b,c)
{
  return expr;
}
```

Inside a single expression you can not use statements like `if` or `var`, but

- parameters with default values can be used as local variables
- conditional expressions `?:` work well instead of `if else`
- you can add more subexpressions using the comma operator or even better as unused parameter to functions. In this case the assignment of `w` is the second (unused) parameter to the function `z`

We can rewrite the `f` function as

```js
f = function(n) {
  var z = function(a) { // use current value of n (that changes)
    return a.repeat(n/2);
  };
  var result;
  if (n > 1) {
    result = '  ' + z('____') + '\n '; // top row if more than 1 triangle
  else
    result = ' '; // else just the blank
  ++n; // increase n, so invert even/odd
  w = ' /'[n&1]+'\n'; //  blank if n is now even, else '/' if n is now odd
  // the next rows will end in "/\" or "\  /" based on n even/odd
  result +=  z('/\\  ') + w; // offset by the blank char added before
  result += z('/__\\') + w;
  return result;
}
```

**Test** in Firefox/FireBug console

```
console.log(f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(9))
```

*Output*

```
 /\   
/__\ 

  ____
 /\  /
/__\/

  ____
 /\  /\   
/__\/__\ 

  ________
 /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/

  ________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\   
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\
```

Comment: Nicely done! I spent far too long yesterday looking to shorten it and at best managed to reproduce the 109 in different ways. -8 is quite the jump.

Comment: Cool. Could you post an explanation? I don't fully understand the use of `w`

Comment: @BadHorse explanation added (really, this time)

Comment: Out of interest I tried to do it without trailing spaces and came up with `n=>(n>1?'  '+'____'.repeat(n/2)+'\n':'')+' /\\ '.repeat(n).slice(0,n*2+2-n%2)+'\n'+'/__\\'.repeat(n).slice(0,n*2+1+n%2)` for 119 (deliberately not using template strings etc. to match your answer).

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell <s>155</s> <s>153</s> <s>139</s> 131 Bytes

I found a slightly different approach that turned out to be shorter than my original method. My original attempt is preserved below. As with before, golfing tips are appreciated.

```
m n=unlines.dropWhile(=="  ").z["  "," /","/"].foldr1 z$map t[1..n]
t n|odd n=["","\\","__\\"]
t _=["____","  /","/"]
z=zipWith(++)
```

Thanks to Nimi for the golfing tips.

---

## Previous Attempt <s>197</s> 179 Bytes

```
t n=putStr.unlines.dropWhile(all(==' ')).z(flip(++))(if odd n then["","\\","__\\"]else repeat"").z(++)["  "," /","/"].map(take(4*div n 2).cycle)$["____","\\  /","__\\/"]
z=zipWith
```

Comment: Some hints for golfing: `(mod n 2)==0` is `even n` or better use `odd n` and swap the `then` and `else` part. `concat.take(div n 2).repeat` is `take(4*div n 2).cycle` because all list elements are of length 4. Assign short names to functions with long names, e.g. `z=zipWith` - then use `z`. You can kick out a few spaces `...repeat""else[...`.

Comment: @nimi Thanks for your hints! Using them, I was able to golf my original solution to 179 bytes. By reconsidering my approach, I was also able to reduce my solution to 155 Bytes.

Comment: Hints, part II: `foldr z["","",""]` is `foldr1 z`, because the list to fold is never empty. Instead of `all(==' ')`  you can use `=="  "` (<- two spaces in-between), because it is used to remove the empty line in case of n = 1 and here the first line is `"  "`. The first definition of `t` can be written in a single line: `t n|odd...`.

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>55</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```
SSri:I2/4*'_*N]I1>*" /\ "I*I)2*<N"/__\\"I*I2*)I2%+<
```

I tried porting my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48113/21487) and it turned out to be shorter than the other CJams.

[Permalink](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=SSri%3AI2%2F4*'_*N%5DI1%3E*%22%20%2F%5C%20%22I*I%292*%3CN%22%2F__%5C%5C%22I*I2*%29I2%25%2B%3C&input=10).

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>73</s> <s>68</s> <s>63</s> <s>62</s> 60 bytes

This definitely needs some golfing...

```
S2*l~:I2/'_4**N]I(g*S"\\  /"'\{I2md@*@@*'/\@}:F~N"__\\/"_W<F
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=S2*l~%3AI2%2F'_4**N%5DI(g*S%22%5C%5C%20%20%2F%22'%5C%7BI2md%40*%40%40*'%2F%5C%40%7D%3AF~N%22__%5C%5C%2F%22_W%3CF&input=5)

### Explanation

```
"Print the first line:";
S2*l~:I2/'_4**N]I(g*

S2*                  "Push a string with 2 spaces.";
   l~:I              "Read and eval the input, store it in I.";
       2/            "Divide by two to get the number of top segments.";
         '_4**       "Push '____' and repeat it by the number of segments.";
              N]     "Push a newline and wrap everything in an array.";
                I(g* "Get sign(I-1) and repeat the array that often. This is a no-op
                      for I > 1 but otherwise empties the array.";

"Print the other two lines. The basic idea is to define block which takes as arguments
 a repeatable 4-character string as well as another string which only gets printed for
 even I.";
S"\\  /"'\{I2md@*@@*'/\@}:F~N"__\\/"_W<F

S                                        "Push a space.";
 "\\__/"'\                               "Push the string '\__/' and the character \.";
          {             }:F~             "Store this block in F and evaluate it.";
           I2md                          "Get I/2 and I%2 using divmod.";
               @*                        "Pull up the second argument and repeat it I%2
                                          times. This turns it into an empty string for
                                          even I.";
                 @@                      "Pull up I/2 and the 4-character string.";
                   *                     "Repeat the string I/2 times.";
                    '/\@                 "Push a / and reorder the three line parts.";
                            N            "Push a newline.";
                             "__\\/"_W<F "Call F again, with '__\/' and '__\'.";
```

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 115 bytes

```r
n->(m=n÷2;p=println;k=n%2>0?m+1:m;e=m<k?"":"/";t=" /\\ ";b="/__\\";if n>1 p("  "*"_"^4m)end;p(t^k*" "*e);p(b^k*e))
```

This creates an unnamed function which accepts an integer and prints the triangles. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=n->(...)`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
function f(n)

    m = n ÷ 2                    # Number of upside down triangles
    p = println                  # Store println function to save space
    k = n % 2 > 0 ? m + 1 : m    # Number of right side up triangles
    e = m < k ? "" : "/"         # n even? End lines with a /

    # Top of the triangle
    t = " /\\ "

    # Bottom of the triangle
    b = "/__\\"

    # Print the bottoms of any upside down triangles
    # * performs string concatenation
    # ^ performs string repetition
    if n > 1
        println("  " * "_"^4m)
    end

    # Print the triangle tops (these have two trailing spaces
    # if the last triangle isn't upside down)
    println(t^k * " " * e)

    # Print the triangle bottoms
    println(b^k * e)
end
```

Example output:

```r
julia> for i = 1:10 f(i) end
 /\  
/__\
  ____
 /\  /
/__\/
  ____
 /\  /\  
/__\/__\
  ________
 /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/
  ________
 /\  /\  /\  
/__\/__\/__\
  ____________
 /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/
  ____________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  
/__\/__\/__\/__\
  ________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/
  ________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\
  ____________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
```

I'm pretty bummed that this is so long. I'm sure there are golfing opportunities aplenty but they aren't clear to me at the moment. Let me know if you have any suggestions or if you'd like any further explanation!

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>68 62</s> 60 bytes

As far as I can see, this is a completely different approach than the other CJam solution. This can be golfed a lot.

```
"/__\\ /\\"4/]ri:R(['/"  /"'_4*"__\\"'\L]3/R*<+zR1>SS+*\W%N*
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%2F__%5C%5C%20%2F%5C%5C%224%2F%5Dri%3AR(%5B'%2F%22%20%20%2F%22'_4*%22__%5C%5C%22'%5CL%5D3%2FR*%3C%2BzR1%3ESS%2B*%5CW%25N*&input=6)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, <s>257</s>183 bytes

```C#
void C(int t){int i;var n="\r\n";var s="  "+string.Join("____",new string[1+t/2])+n;for(i=0;i++<=t;)s+=i%2<1?"\\ ":" /";s+=n;for(i=0;i++<=t;)s+=i%2<1?"__\\":"/";Console.WriteLine(s);}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to the tips from @VisualMelon, saved 74 bytes.

I know it's far from the best language to golf in, but I'm mostly interested in learning about the various nuances of C#, rather than winning the competition.
This is basically a port of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/48101/15417) Pyth answer.

I'm thinking the for loops could be golfed further, but I'm not quite sure how, given the tertiary statements embedded within them.

Example (1, 2, 3, 10):

```
 /\   
/__\  
  ____
 /\  /
/__\/
  ____
 /\  /\ 
/__\/__\
  ____________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
```

**Ungolfed:**

```C#
void C2(int t)
{
    int i;
    var n="\r\n";
    var s="  "+string.Join("____",new string[1+t/2])+n;
    for(i=0;i++<=t;)
        s+=i%2<1?"\\ ":" /";
    s+=n;
    for(i=0;i++<=t;)
        s+=i%2<1?"__\\":"/";
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: While StringBuilders are fast and lovely, if you want a low byte count, `s+=` is your friend. Indeed, you're for loops can be made a bit more compact. The joy/horror of the `++` and `--` operators means you can do most of the work in the conditional check `for(i=0;i++<=t;)` (this checks if `i` is less than or equal to `t` _then_ increments it). You'd do well to define the `int i` outside the for loop, and reuse it, and since you can guarantee that `i` will never be negative, `i%2==0` can be swapped for `i%2<1`. With these changes, a sub 200byte score is easily attained.

Comment: Also, I suspect you wrote this up in LINQPad or similar, because access to `Enumerable` usually requires a `using System.Linq` directive, and I think it's generally intended that such clauses are included. _However_, in this instance the only LINQ can be replaced with `var s="  "+string.Join("____",new string[1+t/2])+n;` which contains no LINQ, and is shorter than the current code ;) It joins lots of null strings together with what we really care about, "____" (the 1+t/2 being because we need another null string to fit another "____" before). The variable `n` is declared as "\r\n".

Comment: Great tips! I forgot that Enumerable would need System.Linq, I barely pay attention these days. The for loop tip is handy!

Comment: A bit late, but you could save 4 bytes by using `Console.Write` instead of `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 3):

### C# 190

```
void f(int n){string s=(n>1)?"\n  ":"",t=" /",u = "/";bool b=true;int m=n;while(m-->0){s+=(n>1&&b&&m>0)?"____":"";t+=b?"\\":"  /";u+=b?"__\\":"/";b=!b;}Console.Write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}",s,t,u);}
```

Ungolfed

```
void f(int n)
{
string s = (n > 1) ? "\n  " : "", t = " /", u = "/";
bool b = true;
int m = n;
while(m-->0)
{
s += (n > 1 && b && m>0) ? "____" : "";
t += b ? "\\" : "  /";
u += b ? "__\\" : "/";
b = !b;
}
Console.Write("{0}\n{1}\n{2}",s,t,u);
}
```

Comment: Nice work! Note that it is never better to use a `while`loop, rather use a `for` loop. In this case you can save 2 bytes by including the definition of `m` in the for loop initialisation, and `b=!b`in the last thing whatever it's called. You can also make savings by replacing `string` and `bool` with `var`. You also don't need the "()" around `n>1` clauses, and in the `s+=` clause you can use the non-short circuiting `&` rather than `&&` as there are no side-effects or dereferences to go wrong. Finally, `1>0` is shorter than `true` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 185

```
String f(int n){int i;String s="";if(n>1){s="  ";for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)s+="____";s+='\n';}for(i=0;i<=n;)s+=i++%2<1?" /":"\\ ";s+='\n';for(i=0;i<=n;i++)s+=i%2<1?i<n?"/_":"/":"_\\";return s;}
```

## Explanation

```
String f(int n) {
    int i;
    String s = "";
    if (n > 1) {
        s = "  ";
        for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
            s += "____";
        }
        s += '\n';
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        s += i % 2 < 1 ? " /" : "\\ ";
    }
    s += '\n';
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        s += i % 2 < 1 ? i < n ? "/_" : "/" : "_\\";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### C# - <s>151</s> <s>146</s> <s>141</s> 138

Inspired by @bacchusbeale's answer

```
string f(int n){string t="\n",s=n>1?"  "+new string('_',n/2*4)+t:"";for(var b=n<0;n-->=0;t+=b?"__\\":"/",b=!b)s+=b?"\\ ":" /";return s+t;}
```

Ungolfed

```
    string f(int n)
    {
        string t = "\n", s = n > 1 ? "  " + new string('_', n / 2 * 4) + t : "";
        for (var b = n < 0; n-- >= 0; t += b ? "__\\" : "/", b = !b)
            s += b ? "\\ " : " /";
        return s + t;
    }
```

Comment: Nice, not sure how I missed this before commenting on the other answers! That overload of `new String` is a new one to me! You seem to have missed your `t=""` from the golfed version, though a better thing to do would be initialize `t` as "\n". You can save a couple of bytes by appending to `t` where you flip `b`, saving the "{}" on the for-loop: `t+=(b=!b)?"/":"__\\"`.

Comment: @tis you can save a couple more if you define `t` before `s` and add `t` to the string rather than `"\n"` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## C89, 150

```
r(p,q,n)int*p,*q;{n?printf(p),r(q,p,n-1):puts(p);}main(c,v)int**v;{c=atoi(v[1]);if(c>1)printf("  "),r("","____",c-1);r(" /","\\ ",c);r("/","__\\",c);}
```

An ungolfed version:

```
r(p, q, n) char *p, *q; {
    if(n > 0) {
        printf(p);
        r(q, p, n-1); /* swap p and q */
    } else {
        puts(p);
    }
}

main(c, v) char**v; {
    c = atoi(v[1]);
    if(c>1) {
        printf("  ");
        r("", "____", c - 1);
    }
    r(" /", "\\ ", c);
    r("/", "__\\", c);
}
```

The output:

```
$ seq 1 3 10 | xargs -n1 ./triangles
 /\
/__\
  ________
 /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/
  ____________
 /\  /\  /\  /\
/__\/__\/__\/__\
  ____________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
```

The stack overflows if I enter `65535` (but not if you compile with `-O3`!), but theoretically it should work ;-)

*edit:* program now fulfills the requirement that only two lines should be outputted if `1` is passed to the program
*edit 2:* use `int*` instead of `char*`

Comment: You could declare `main` as `main(c,v)**v;` if that works.

Comment: I was wondering if you could save something by  having `c` or `n` as a global variable, so you don't have to pass that parameter to `r()`. I don't think your answer complies with `Note that for 1 the output is two lines long but otherwise it's three. This is required.`

Comment: @FUZxxl unfortunately this doesn't work :-( `error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘*’ token main(c,v)**v;{`

Comment: @steveverrill fixed it, but I needed to lenghten the code. Couldn't find a solution with a global `n` or `c` that's shorter either.

Comment: @MarcDefiant Were you able to pass an `int**`?

Comment: @FUZxxl thank you, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

## Go, <del>156</del> 144

```
func f(n int){a,b,c:="  ","","";for i:=0;i<=n;i++{if i<n/2{a+="____"};if i%2<1{b+=" /";c+="/"}else{b+=`\ `;c+=`__\`}};print(a+"\n"+b+"\n"+c)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
func f(n int) {
    a, b, c := "  ", "", ""   // Initialize 3 accumulators
    for i := 0; i <= n; i++ { // For each required triangle
        if i < n/2 {          // Yay integer math
            a += "____"
        }
        if i%2 < 1 {          // Even, uneven, (are we drawing up or downslope?)
            b += " /"
            c += "/"
        } else {
            b += `\ `
            c += `__\`
        }
    }
    print(a + "\n" + b + "\n" + c)
}
```

The only real trick here (and it isn't even a good one) is using 3 accumulators so I can condense the solution down to 1 loop.

The code can be run here: http://play.golang.org/p/urEO1kIjKv

Comment: simply use ``c += `__\` `` instead of the `if i<n{c+="_"}`

Comment: @MarcDefiant Updated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>166</s> <s>127</s> <s>125</s> <s>119</s> 105 bytes

```
printf -v l %$[$1/2]s;(($1%2))&&r= j=$l\ ||r=/ j=$l;echo "  ${l// /____}
${j// / /\ } $r
${j// //__\\}"$r
```

In a function:

```
triangle() {
    printf -v l %$[$1/2]s;(($1%2))&&r= j=$l\ ||r=/ j=$l;echo "  ${l// /____}
${j// / /\ } $r
${j// //__\\}"$r
}
```

With some presentations:

```
for i in {1..5} 10 31;do
    paste -d\  <(
        figlet -fsmall $i |
             sed 's/^/         /;s/^ *\(.\{10\}\)$/\1  /;$d'
    ) <(triangle $i)
  done
```

May render (if you have *figlet* installed):

```
        _      
       / |    /\  
       | |   /__\
       |_|   
      ___      ____
     |_  )    /\  /
      / /    /__\/
     /___|   
      ____     ____
     |__ /    /\  /\  
      |_ \   /__\/__\
     |___/   
     _ _       ________
    | | |     /\  /\  /
    |_  _|   /__\/__\/
      |_|    
      ___      ________
     | __|    /\  /\  /\  
     |__ \   /__\/__\/__\
     |___/   
   _  __       ____________________
  / |/  \     /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
  | | () |   /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
  |_|\__/    
    _____      ____________________________________________________________
   |__ / |    /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  
    |_ \ |   /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\
   |___/_|
```

#### Save 2 chars if *input* from variable instead of `$1`: 103

```
printf -v l %$[i/2]s;((i%2))&&r= j=$l\ ||r=/ j=$l;echo "  ${l// /____}
${j// / /\ } $r
${j// //__\\}"$r
```

Into the loop:

```
for i in {1..3} {31..34};do
    [ $i == 31 ] && figlet -fsmall ...
    paste -d\  <(
        figlet -fsmall $i |
            sed 's/^/         /;s/^ *\(.\{10\}\)$/\1   /;$d'
    ) <(
        printf -v l %$[i/2]s;((i%2))&&r= j=$l\ ||r=/ j=$l;echo "  ${l// /____}
${j// / /\ } $r
${j// //__\\}"$r
    )
  done
```

Will render (approx) same:

```
        _       
       / |     /\  
       | |    /__\
       |_|    
      ___       ____
     |_  )     /\  /
      / /     /__\/
     /___|    
      ____      ____
     |__ /     /\  /\  
      |_ \    /__\/__\
     |___/    
       
       
 _ _ _ 
(_|_|_)
       
    _____       ____________________________________________________________
   |__ / |     /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  
    |_ \ |    /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\
   |___/_|    
  _______       ________________________________________________________________
 |__ /_  )     /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
  |_ \/ /     /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
 |___/___|    
  ________      ________________________________________________________________
 |__ /__ /     /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  
  |_ \|_ \    /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\
 |___/___/    
 _____ _        ____________________________________________________________________
|__ / | |      /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
 |_ \_  _|    /__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
|___/ |_|
```

Comment: You should post a question about a figlet implementation codegolf!

Answer (score 1):

## [><> (Fish)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <strike>215</strike> <strike>183</strike> 156 bytes

Edit: Notepad++ was giving me 5 extra bytes due to CR, so modified count accordingly

Slightly more golfed, but it is my first fish program so far >_< The requirement to not have a blank first line for 1 triangle doubled the size of the program.

```
99+0{:}1=?.~~"  "oo:2,:1%-v
-1  oooo  "____"  v!?  )0:/!
" /"oa~~.?=1}:{24~/:oo
v!?)0:-1o"\"v!?)0:/!-1ooo"  /"
/v   ~o"/"oa/!
!\:0)?!;"\__"ooo1-:0)?!;"/"o1-
```

Can test at http://fishlanguage.com/ (Int on initial stack for length)

Explanation:

```
       Start with initial stack as input number
99+0   Push 18 and 0 to the top of the stack
{:}    Shift the stack to the left (wraps), copy the top value, and shift it back to the left (i.e. copy bottom of stack to the top)
1=     Check to see if the top of the stack is equal to 1, pushes 1 for true, 0 for false
?.     If top of stack is zero, skip the ., otherwise jumps to x,y coordinates on top of stack (18,0). This skips the next 8 instructions
~~     Pop the top 2 values from the stack (if they're not popped by the jump)
"  "   Push the string literal "  " onto the stack
oo     Pop the top two values of stack and output them as characters
:2,    Copy top value of stack, ad divide by 2
:1%-   Since ><> uses float division, and doesn't have >= notation, remove the decimal part (if exists)
v      Redirect pointer down
/      Redirect pointer left
:0)    Copy top of stack, and see if its greater than 0 (1 for true, 0 for false)
?!v    If top of stack is non-zero, then ! is executed, which skips the next instruction (redirect), otherwise, code is redirected
"____" Push the literal "____" to the stack
oooo   Pop the top four values of stack and output them as characters
1-     Decrement the top of the stack by 1
!/     Ignore the redirect action.
       When the loop gets to 0, it goes to next line, and gets redirected to the left.
~      Pops the top of the stack (0 counter)
42     Pushes 4 and 2 to the stack
{:}    As before, copies the bottom of the stack to the top
1=?.   Also as before, if the initial value is 1, jump to (2,4) (skipping next 4 instructions
~~     Pop 2 values from stack if these instructions haven't been skipped
ao     Push 10 onto the stack and output it as a character (LF)
"/ "oo Push the literal "/ " onto the stack and output it
://    Copies the top of the stack then redirects to the line below, which then redirects to the left
:0)    Copies top of the stack and compares if its greater than 0
?!v    If it is, redirect to next line
"\"o   Push "\" to stack, then output it as a character
1-     Decrement top value of stack
:0)?!v If loop is not greater than 0, redirect to next line
       Either mode of redirect will loop to the left, and (potentially) skip the far right redirect because of the !
ao     Push 10 to stack and output it as a character (LF)
"/"o~  Push "/" to stack, then output it as a character. Pop top value of stack (the 0 from previous loop)
v      Redirects to next line, which then redirects to the right
:0)?!; If the top of the stack is not greater than 0, terminate (;)
"\__"  Pushes "\__" to the stack
ooo    Outputs top 3 stack values as characters ("__\")
1-     Decrement top of stack by 1
:0)?!; If the top of the stack is not greater than 0, terminate (;)
"/"o   Push "/" to top of stack then output it as a character
1-     Decrement top of stack by 1
!\     Ignore the redirect
```

Comment: Nice interpreter! Did you make that yourself?

Comment: Not even slightly. :P I used it extensively to teach myself the language...and to debug. I just saw the language floating around and thought it was very interesting (also want to try Marbles).

Answer (score 1):

## perl <strike>109</strike> <strike>108</strike> 106

```
$i=<>;$t=join$/,$i-1?"  "."_"x($i/2)x4:(),$m.=(" /")[$_&1]||"\\ ",$b.=("/")[$_&1]||"__\\"for 0..$i;print$t
```

I think this is alright for my first golf, I used Vynce's section for the first line, with the rest of my code to get past the new line problem with 1 triangle.

Now to see if I can shorten it :)

**Edit**: Whitespace

**Edit 2**: replaced `"\n"` with `$/`

```
1:
 /\
/__\

4:
  ________
 /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ stdlib, 194 bytes

```
string f(int n){char* p[]={"____"," /\\ ","/__\\"};int x[]={(n-n%2)*2,n*2+2-n%2,n*2+1+n%2},i,j;string s=n>1?"  ":"";for (i=n>1?0:1;i<3;s+=++i<3?"\n":"")for (j=0;j<x[i];)s+=p[i][j++%4];return s;}
```

Test program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string f(int n)
{
    char* p[]={"____"," /\\ ","/__\\"};
    int x[]={(n-n%2)*2,n*2+2-n%2,n*2+1+n%2},i,j;
    string s=n>1?"  ":"";
    for (i=n>1?0:1;i<3;s+=++i<3?"\n":"")
        for (j=0;j<x[i];)
            s+=p[i][j++%4];
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << f(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 27 bytes

```
ＦＥＮ﹪ι²«Ｐ×⁴_↗⊗¬ι↓Ｐ↘²↘⊗ι↑Ｐ↗⊗ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY09C8IwFEXn9leETi@QLsXFunZxSBGxs/Qj2gdpX4hJHcTfHiEoFh3v4d5z@7G1PbU6hAtZBrI1sJ@Nd7WfOmWBCyZp8JoABSs45@yRJtJrh8bi7OCEk7rBRrDsnHG@S5NDxGVjjngdnWAV@U6rAWpygDxWJC0Kyoruc0xfWWTvXbGSrfBHhytTY349f@@x/gxhG/JFvwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＥＮ﹪ι²«
```

Generate a list of alternating bits of length `n` and loop over them.

```
Ｐ×⁴_
```

Draw `____` without moving the cursor.

```
↗⊗¬ι↓
```

On the first and every other triangle, draw the left `/` side.

```
Ｐ↘²
```

Draw the `\` side without moving the cursor.

```
↘⊗ι↑
```

On the second and every other triangle, draw the left `\` side again to move the cursor.

```
Ｐ↗⊗ι
```

On the second and every other triangle, draw the right `/` side, without moving the cursor.

Comment: Answers no longer have to be marked as non-competing anymore

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>116</s> 95 bytes

<sup>Big thanks to Mazzy and ASCII-Only for saving 21 bytes</sup>

```powershell
param($n)@("  "+"_"*4*($x=$n-shr1))[$n-eq1]
" /"+"\  /"*$x+"\"*($a=$n%2)
"/"+"__\/"*$x+"__\"*$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCsIwEEX3OcUwTCWJWInosuA9rIQsIl3U2qYLC7VnH7/g6j94D/74eucyd7nvVR7U0KpjKulpZXBXy0S858j@7K0sjQyHuSvBuRsoT@FumI4IWsJ4WUCMMCGsTs7wz8XY/h0IkHQzoa4vn2rd4VDiphq@)

Not allowing an empty line for n = 1 ate up like <s>14</s> 10 bytes. This solution is <s>pretty brain dead</s> now much more clever with a minimal amount of repeated code. Banker's Rounding is still the actual devil.

Comment: Is an empty line not allowed???

Comment: @ASCII-only Read the 4th bullet point from the OP.

Comment: [damnit](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPU0NHQ0lBQUlbKR4IlLSifRNLMmKtrNxy8vOLgPL6RpqamtGKQJauoWYsl5KCfoyCkpaGSoUtTKVzamZOZl46VK02UAVQ3lBXJU/VSJNLST8@PkZJS6VCWwlJ@P///4YA)

Comment: [here we go](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPU0NHQ0lBQUlbKR4IlLSAQvpGmpqa0YpAlq6hZiyXkoJ@jAJIosI22jexJCPWyso5NTMnMy8dqlYbqAIob6irkqdqpMmlpB8fH6OkpVKhrYQk/P//fyMDAA)

Comment: [102 on yours](https://tio.run/##LcpBCoAgEIXhfaewYQJHC6l9J9EQF0ELs6hF3n7S6O1@vncez3rd2xoj8xmusEtMJHsJQoAGXwZKYp4xmYmIbFt8GGlpQBgnQGHW5Wugrw1kMXVTQeO9@7Halz8y8/gC)

Comment: @ASCII-only [Breaks on x = 3](https://tio.run/##LcpBCoAgEIXhfaewYQJHC6nWncRCXAgtyqIWefvJwrf7@d55POG617BtzKe//C4xkmwlCAEaXB4oiWnCaAYisnX2rqelAmFmAQqTzl8D7ddAFmMzZDTOzQU/@7MgM48v) The string replace is how you bypass banker's rounding

Comment: @mazzy you can't generate a first line, otherwise it'd be [102](https://tio.run/##LcnBCoQgFIXhfU8hhxupNUnte5IcREJo4ZjYot7@VkNndX6@vB2h7GuIkTn74n@SkoIQaOHuQUs6J0pm/JSQo19CY/teN6qCMFZA09nK@6J7GmqmVI/fCsY5@@Jj/3yRmYcL)

Comment: [100?](https://tio.run/##LYxLCoAwEEP3nqIMI0z9UBS3PYmKdFFw4d@F3n6MYiAkPEK29YrHOcZpUt3CEWbhxUohZAzlNECUCd8euBQOnpe0ttbBtgWKe9UnZBy2nUFkfKMhQkLuO@h@iPZiVW0e)

Comment: [close, but not quite 100](https://tio.run/##PYs7CoAwEAV7TxGWCLv@otHWk6gEi4CKxl@ht1@38nXzmDn2x1/35NeV@RivcUMdCDMEpSAFJ4ME5ct1iC0ZS0SdkD@rIcqXfQ5iml5BIllXFgXqt7UCaU2/YJzrf0G/AzM3Hw)

Comment: 96 bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jc1BCoMwEIXhfU4xDGMxCSpT2mXAe9QSXKS4sKmNQgX17OmU7h7fv3jT6xPSPIRxzPQAB1ue@tQ/S4q6LREALXo0FyNQzUNirW@ywpvvCqHpAKWsjqLlf7aiP1scVxSLs1bYeN@hodWiFFryobiur3uxneSR/JEzfwE "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88277/discussion-between-ascii-only-and-mazzy).

Answer (score 0):

## C, 368 Bytes

```
void p(char* c){printf(c);}
int x(int s,int f){int t=0,p=s;for(int i=0;i<f;i++){if(p==1){t++;p=0;}else{p=1;}}return t;}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]){int t=atoi(argv[1]);if(t>1){p("  ");for(int i=0;i<x(0,t);i++)
{p("____");}p("\n");}for(int i=0;i<x(1,t);i++){p(" /\\ ");}if(t%2==0){p(" /");}p("\n");
for(int i=0;i<x(1,t);i++){p("/__\\");}if(t%2==0){p("/");}p("\n");}
```

It's more if you count the `#include` statements, but it compiled on gcc, albeit with warnings, without them. I know it's not the shortest by far, but I still like that I did it in C.

Comment: The macro `#define p(c)printf(c)` is shorter than your function. You can omit return types on functions (they default to `int`). You can also define function in `C89` style like this `main(c,v)char**v;{}`. That is short for `int main(int c, char** v){}`

Answer (score 0):

## Perl (simple) <strike>131</strike> <strike>125</strike> 120

fairly straightforward first pass:

```
$i=<>;print join"\n",$i-1?"  "."_"x(4*int($i/2)):(),join("",map{(" /","\\ ")[$_%2]}0..$i),join"",map{("/","__\\")[$_%2]}0..$i
```

oh who needs explicit int?

```
$i=<>;print join"\n",$i-1?"  "."_"x($i/2)x4:(),join("",map{(" /","\\ ")[$_%2]}0..$i),join"",map{("/","__\\")[$_%2]}0..$i
```

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog, 126 bytes

```
A+B:-writef(A,B).
$N:-(N>1,"  %r\n"+['____',N//2];!),(0is N/\1,T='/';T='')," %r%w\n"+['/\\  ',N/2,T],"%r%w\n"+['/__\\',N/2,T].
```

Invoke like `$3`.

More readable:

```
triangle(N):-
    (   N > 1
    ->  writef("  %r\n", ['____', N//2])
    ;   true
    ),
    (   0 is N mod 2
    ->  T = '/'
    ;   T = ''
    ),
    writef(" %r%w\n", ['/\\  ', N/2, T]),
    writef("%r%w\n", ['/__\\', N/2, T]).
```

Example:

```
?- findall(N,between(1,10,N),NN), maplist($, NN), !.
 /\  
/__\
  ____
 /\  /
/__\/
  ____
 /\  /\  
/__\/__\
  ________
 /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/
  ________
 /\  /\  /\  
/__\/__\/__\
  ____________
 /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/
  ____________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  
/__\/__\/__\/__\
  ________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/
  ________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\
  ____________________
 /\  /\  /\  /\  /\  /
/__\/__\/__\/__\/__\/
NN = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...].
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#: 1 line LINQ, 198 bytes

```
string f(int n){return(n>1?"  ":"")+string.Join("\n",new[]{"____"," /\\ ","/__\\"}.Zip(new[]{(n-n%2)*2,n*2+2-n%2,n*2+1+n%2},(s,l)=>string.Join(s,new string[n+1]).Substring(0,l)).Where(x=>x.Any()));}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 88 bytes

```
K`  ____¶ /\  /¶/__\/
%`....$
$+*$&
%`(.+)\1$
$1
(  (____)*)__(¶.*)  /(¶.*)/
$1$3$4
G`\S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/3ztBQSEeCA5tU9CPUVDQP7RNPz4@Rp9LNUEPCFS4VLS1VNSAPA09bc0YQyDfkEtDQUEDpEVTSzM@XuPQNj0tTaBGCEMfqEDFWMWEyz0hJvj/f0sA) Explanation:

```
K`  ____¶ /\  /¶/__\/
```

Replace the input with a pair of triangles.

```
%`....$
$+*$&
```

Multiply the triangles by the original input.

```
%`(.+)\1$
$1
```

Divide the triangles by 2.

```
(  (____)*)__(¶.*)  /(¶.*)/
$1$3$4
```

Remove the left-over half triangle.

```
G`\S
```

Remove the first line if it is now blank.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 83 bytes

```perl6
{~["  {'____'x$_/2-.5}
"x($_>2),'/\  'x$_/2~($!='/'x$_%2),"
"~'/__\\'x$_/2~$!]}o*+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ui5aSUGhWj0eCNQrVOL1jXT1TGu5lCo0VOLtjDR11PVjFBQgEnUaKoq26vogjipQRolLqU5dPz4@JgYqraIYW5uvpW3435pLTy1NrzixUiEtv0jBUE/P9D8A)

Anonymous code block that takes a number and returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>117</s> 115 bytes

-2 thanks to ceilingcat.

All those parentheses suggest something less clunky is surely possible.

```c
f(n,i,j){for(j=3-1/n;j--;puts("/"+(n%2|j>1)))for(i=0;i<n+(j<2)>>1;)printf("  %.4s"+2-j*!i++,"/__\\/\\  ____"+j*4);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BCoMwEEXX5hTTgDBjTNNYd1FPEpAipCTQVNSurGdPI/2b9xkew5/kc5pSchhrXwfa3XvB0N@lVtEEKc382VbkiguMZfMNgyai0/H9zfguCgxdQ8OgDc2Lj5tDDlBe25WLRobq4oWouRpHa5W1AGMOF6FqyRwp6/B6@IjEdlbkp4DnyUMP2mR0mbdchCBWZKNw6Mlk/jfxsx/sSD8)

Comment: [this might be a start for something less clunky. _might_.](https://tio.run/##NY2xDoMwDETn5CuytLIJSCGoQzGUb0GRaB2poUJ0QvDrqRk6vfOddReqZwg5T5BKLiNu07xA7B3FrqFoLZ43941NhaeDq4rw813Da1zg4CEOruVOIltf@eELSBePw/3WNr6tHdKeOa3mPXIC1JtWUmbgtNj0piZBJ3QiZEkr@VATMJLwv3LWaLXrPf8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
≠iðð'_I2÷4*×J}„ /„\ ‚I>∍J'/…__\‚I>∍J»
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UeeCzMMbDm9Qj/c0OrzdROvwdK/aRw3zFPSBRIzCo4ZZnnaPOnq91IH8ZfHxMXCBQ7v//zcGAA) or [verify the first 10 outputs](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i6ufyqGHe4f1WOv8fdS7IPLzh8Ab1eD@jw9tNtA5P96oFyinoA4kYhUcNs/zsHnX0eqkD@cvi42PgAod2/9c5tM3@PwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
≠i            } # If the (implicit) input is NOT 1:
                #   i.e. 1 → 0 (falsey)
                #   i.e. 5 → 1 (truthy)
  ðð            #  Push two spaces "  "
    '_         '#  Push string "_"
      I         #  Push the input
       2÷       #  Integer-divide it by 2
                #   i.e. 5 → 2
         4*     #  And then multiply it by 4
                #   i.e. 2 → 8
           ×    #  Repeat the "_" that many times
                #   i.e. "_" and 8 → "________"
            J   #  Join everything on the stack together to a single string
                #   i.e. "  ________"
„ /             # Push string " /"
   „\           # Push string "\ "
     ‚          # Pair them together: [" /","\ "]
      I>        # Push the input+1
        ∍       # Extend the list to that size
                #  i.e. [" /","\ "] and 2 → [" /","\ "]
                #  i.e. [" /","\ "] and 6 → [" /","\ "," /","\ "," /","\ "]
         J      # Join the list together to a single string
                #  i.e. [" /","\ "] → " /\ "
                #  i.e. [" /","\ "," /","\ "," /","\ "] → " /\  /\  /\ "
'/             '# Push string "/"
  …__\          # Push string "__\"
      ‚         # Pair them together: ["/","__\"]
       I>       # Push the input+1
         ∍      # Extend the list to that size
                #  i.e. ["/","__\"] and 2 → ["/","__\"]
                #  i.e. ["/","__\"] and 6 → ["/","__\","/","__\","/","__\"]
          J     # Join the list together to a single string
                #  i.e. ["/","__\"] → "/__\"
                #  i.e. ["/","__\","/","__\","/","__\"] → "/__\/__\/__\"
»               # Join the entire stack with a newline delimiter
                #  i.e. " /\ " and "/__\" → " /\ \n/__\"
                #  i.e. "  ________", " /\  /\  /\ " and "/__\/__\/__\"
                #   → "  ________\n /\  /\  /\ \n/__\/__\/__\"
                # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 11, 122 bytes

```java
n->(n>1?"  "+"_".repeat(n/2*4)+"\n":"")+" /\\ ".repeat(n).substring(0,++n*2)+"\n"+"/__\\".repeat(n).substring(0,n/2*4+n%2)
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fZBBbsMgEEX3OcUIqRKEBsdWVnWcnqDZdFkqizikInHGlsGRqspndyfYUlfpBhj@h3l/zuZmVufjZaxq4z28GYc/CwCHwXYnU1nY30uA99A5/IKKkwIocrocFrT4YIKrYA8IBYy42nHcpa8MgElWMtXZ1prAMcmWGyGZRvbCGB0g0Rr@ZKF8f/CxBV8/S4nLbHJLlpSl1o@c8V@JT5kY8ztN2x9qopmhbo07wpUS8Yn@4xOMmOKcmi4mcUWag9sW6Zo2KWeV4n77YK@q6YNq6WmokTtJ7DH4AwMqmo74zzFrQxzeMP4C)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->                   // Method with integer parameter and String return-type
  (n>1?               //  If the input is larger than 1:
    "  "              //   Return two spaces
    +"_".repeat(      //   Appended with "_" repeated the following amount of times:
          n/2         //    The input integer-divided by 2
             *4)      //    And then multiplied by 4
    +"\n"             //   Appended with a newline
   :                  //  Else:
    "")               //   Return nothing
  +" /\\ ".repeat(n)  //  Appended with " /\ " repeated the input amount of times
    .substring(0,     //   After which we only leave the first `x` characters, where `x` is:
      ++n             //    Increase the input by 1 first with `++n`
         *2)          //    And then multiply it by 2
                      //     i.e. For input 1, `x` becomes 4 here
                      //     i.e. For input 6, `x` becomes 14 here
  +"\n"               //  Appended with a newline
  +"/__\\".repeat(n)  //  Appended with "/__\" repeated the input amount of times
    .substring(0,     //   After which we only leave the first `y` characters, where `y` is:
      n/2             //    The input+1 integer-divided by 2
         *4           //    Then multiplied by 4
           +n%2)      //    And then the input+1 modulo-2 added
                      //     i.e. For input 1, `y` becomes 4 here
                      //     i.e. For input 6, `y` becomes 13 here
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 35 bytes

```
½û__∞* ∞qpÿ /\ *k∞⌠<p)½ÿ/__\*k¥┬'/*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q3sO74@MfdczTUgAShQWH9yvoxyhoZQM5j3oW2BRoAhXs14@Pj9HKPrT00ZQ16vpa//8bchlxGXOZcJlymRr8100BAA)

### Explanation

The program is split into 3 parts, `½û__∞* ∞qp`, `ÿ /\ *k∞⌠<p`, and `)½ÿ/__\*k¥┬'/*`. One part for each line of the output.

#### First part

```
½           Halve input to integer
 û__∞       Push "__" and double
     *      Repeat string (input//2 times)
       ∞    Push space character and double
        qp  Print the spaces first, then the underscores
```

#### Second part

```
ÿ /\ *      Push " /\ " and repeat it <input> times
      k∞    Push input and double it
        ⌠   Increment by two
         <p Slice the string to get the first (<input>*2 + 2) characters and print
```

#### Third part

```
)½              Increment input by 1 and halve it to integer
  ÿ/__\*        Repeat "/__\" that many times
        k¥┬     Check if input is divisible by 2
           '/*  Repeat "/" either zero or one times based on input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 151 bytes

Without LINQ - 3 string array.

Like most of these, this fails if the integer goes over the  max char count per line for stdout.

```cs
p=>{var s=new string[3]{ "  ","",""};for(var j=0;j< p;){if(j++%2<1){s[1]+=j==p-1?@" /":@" /\ ";s[2]+=j==p-1?@"/":@"/__\";}else s[0]+="____";}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNa8MwDIbPza94MQwS0u@yyxx3g8FOGwx22CENIUvc4pA6wXI6Rshvz5y2g/WVsLAeS0LOaZbXRg4tKX3Axw9ZeeReXmVEeDf1wWTHzgOa9qtSOchm1oVTrQq8ZUr7wQiBl1bnkdJ2Sta4PnGyRQExNGLbnTIDElp@48o2SQcGsCkbvef72vjjo1IseRmh4UGn9n4ZhnfraBV0FK@SUJRCNLPV4xPDgj2M5w6MU7z@j85kkaY7xntZkQTFS8dZ6uRSRtrWaBDvB@65obhOxZKjRISNC2EYnPf5U3dzG3X5oflzramu5PzTKCtflZZ@4a/vg7hMAu5NJjdlvTfa8As)