# N numbers closest to zero staying balanced

Tags: code-golf, math, number, number-theory

**Objective**: Given a positive integer `n`:

- If `n` is odd, output the list of `n` numbers closest to `0` in increasing order
- If `n` is even, output a Falsey value.

**Test cases**:

```
5 -> [-2,-1,0,1,2]
4 -> false (or any Falsey value)
1 -> [0]
```

---

### Reference implementation

```js
function update(){
  var num = +document.getElementById("yield").value;
  if(num){
    var out = document.getElementById("output");
    if(num % 2 == 1){
      // base is balanced
      var baseArr = [];
      for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
        baseArr.push(i-Math.floor(num/2));
      }
      out.innerHTML = baseArr.join(" ");
    } else {
      out.innerHTML = "false";
    }
  } else {
    out.innerHTML = "<i>enter input</i>";
  }
}

setInterval(update,1);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Constantia", "Consolas", monospace;
}

[type="number"] {
  width: 10px;
  width: 2em;
}

#output {
  font-family: "Consolas", monospace;
}
```

```html
Input: <input type="number" id="yield" value="3"> is <span id="output"><i>enter input</i></span>
```

Comment: Can the output be a range object rather than a list?

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Sorry, a range object is an invalid output.

Comment: The empty list is not always falsey.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 In which contexts?

Comment: There are languages (I.E. Javascript) in which the empty list is considered a truthy value.

Comment: @SuperJedi224 so it is...

Comment: I know it's been a while, but can we use `[0]` as falsey result, even though \$n=1\$ results in `[0]` as truthy result as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
*-R/Q2Q%Q2
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2a-R%2FQ2Q%25Q2&input=3)

#### How it works

```
            (implicit) Store the input in Q.
   /Q2      Calculate Q/2 (integer division).
 -R   Q     Subtract that value (-R) from each element in [0, ..., Q-1] (Q).
*      %Q2  Repeat the resulting array Q%2 times.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```
OddQ@#&&Range@#-(#+1)/2&
```

Code-golfing trick: The last argument to `And` doesn't have to be a boolean.

Comment: You can save a byte by using the Unicode brackets for `Floor`.

Comment: Also, `Range[-a,a=...]` seems to work, saving another byte.

Comment: `OddQ@#&&Range@#-(#+1)/2&`

Answer (score 5):

### APL, <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

Thanks to @Dennis for -2 bytes!

```
⌊(⍳⊢×2|⊢)-÷∘2
```

This is a monadic train that gives an empty array for even input. Below is the diagram:

```
┌────┴─────┐   
⌊ ┌────────┼─┐ 
┌─┴─┐      - ∘ 
⍳ ┌─┼───┐   ┌┴┐
  ⊢ × ┌─┼─┐ ÷ 2
      2 | ⊢
```

First, `⊢×2|⊢` gives the input times its mod 2; that is, odds will give themselves, and evens give 0. We use `⍳` to create a list of numbers from 1 to that (`⍳0` gives the empty array), and then we subtract half the input and floor.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
%₂1&~l≠≜o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/VRU5OhWl3Oo84Fjzrn5P//b/rfEQA)

#### Explanation

An interesting (ab)use of Brachylog's backtracking algorithm:

```
%₂1        First, assert that the input mod 2 is 1 (if not, the predicate fails)
   &       Then, the input
    ~l      is the length of some list
      ≠     in which all elements are different
       ≜   Generate a list that matches those conditions
           Brachylog will try to fill the array with integers, starting from 0 and
            increasing in absolute value; since they all have to be different, the result
            will be of the form [0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...]
        o  Sort ascending
```

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, <s>37</s> <s>36</s> 31 bytes

```
g n=take(n*mod n 2)[-div n 2..]
```

Unbalanced is indicated by the empty list. Usage example: `g 7` ->
`[-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]`.

@xnor found 5 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Is there no way to make the empty list case a condition? Doing `g n=[x|x<-[-div n 2..(n+1)/2],odd n]` is equally long.

Comment: 34: `g n=[1|odd n]>>[-div n 2..div n 2]`

Comment: You should edit it in, it's a small change.

Comment: `g n=[1|odd n]>>take n[-div n 2..]` also saves a char.

Comment: @xnor: you're golfing it down faster than I can edit my posts.

Comment: I'd like something like `g n=take(sum[n|odd n])[-div n 2..]` to work, but it's 34 chars.

Comment: `g n=take(n*mod n 2)[-div n 2..]`

Comment: @xnor: thanks again! Unfortunately the challenge now requires a falsey value for the unbalanced case.  As `[]` is not falsey in Haskell, the answer is now invalid.

Comment: Is only False falsey? Do you have to Either?

Comment: @xnor: there's the `Maybe` type, i.e.   `Just [-1,0,1]` or `Nothing`, but I think according to meta a falsey value must work within a `if ... then .. else`, so I'm afraid only `Bool` (`True`or `False`) fits.

Comment: @xnor: there's `listToMaybe` which turns the empty list into `Nothing` and a non empty list `l` into `Just l`, but it needs the `Data.Maybe` import.

Comment: @xnor: ... sorry a mistake `listToMaybe` makes `Just (head l)` in the non empty case, i.e. only the first element of `l` is wrapped into `Just`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>44</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

[<sup>crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(</sup>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61414/42545)

```
n=>[...Array(n&1&&n--)].map((x,i)=>i-n/2)
```

For odd inputs, returns a integer array of length `x`, centered at `0`; for even, returns 0. I think this is as short as it can get. (Saved a couple bytes thanks to @edc65 and @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ!)

ES6 alternative: (42 bytes, thanks to @intrepidcoder)

```
x=>x%2&&[for(y of Array(x--).keys())y-x/2]
```

Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Using `x%2&&[for(y of...]` saves a byte.

Comment: ES6, 43, `n=>Array(n&1&&n--).fill().map((x,i)=>i-n/2)` if returning an empty array is allowed

Comment: @intrepidcoder Thanks! I've changed this.

Comment: @edc65 Thanks as well! I've added this into the answer.

Comment: `x=>x%2&&[for(y of Array(x--).keys())y-x/2]` is 42.

Comment: @intrepidcoder Thanks again!

Comment: 42 for ES6 too `n=>Array(n&1&&n).fill(n=-n>>1).map(x=>++n)`

Comment: 41: `n=>[...Array(n&1&&n--)].map((x,i)=>i-n/2)` for the ES6 entry

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ and edc65 Holy cow, this is getting ridiculous ;) Thanks for the help! I wonder if 40 is possible...

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, <s>50</s> 52 Bytes

```
param($a)$b=$a/2-.5;(0,((0-$b)..$b-join' '))[($a%2)]
```

Oof. Pretty verbose answer. Takes input `$a`, then sets a new variable `$b` as the "floor" of `$a/2`. Generates a new number range from `(0-$b)` to `$b`, then `join`s the range with spaces, and has that as the second element of a two-element array (the first element is `0`). Then uses `$a%2` to index into that array for output.

Alternate version using more "traditional" if/else flow, at 54 bytes:

```
param($a)$b=$a/2-.5;if($a%2){(0-$b)..$b-join' ';exit}0
```

<sub>Edit - Needed to add some logic to output a falsey value if the input is even</sub>

Comment: Save 3 bytes by changing `(0-$b)` to just `-$b`.  Also, just multiplying by `*0` will output a null string (evaluates to false in powershell). (see: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63005/45925)

Answer (score 4):

## J, 12 bytes

```
i:@%~2&!*2&|
```

This is a monadic verb that returns `0` (falsy) for even numbers. Try it online with [J.js](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(i%3A%40%25~2%26!*2%26%7C)%203).

#### Test run

```
   (i:@%~2&!*2&|) 3
_1 0 1
   (i:@%~2&!*2&|) 2
0
```

#### How it works

```
              Right argument: y
         2&|  Take y modulo 2.
     2&!      Calculate y C 2 = y(y-1)/2.
        *     Multiply the results.
   %~         Divide the product by y.
              This yields (y-1)*(y%2)/2 = (y-1)/2 (y even) | 0 (y odd).
  @           Take the result and...
i:              apply the bilateral index generator z -> (-z ... z).
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, <s>34</s> 32 Bytes

Right now I'm not sure if I can output whatever I want if it's not balanced, so currently this just returns an empty list in the case of an unbalance-able base. It's an anonymous lambda function, so give it a name to use it.

```py
lambda k:k%2*range(-k/2+1,-~k/2)
```

Comment: If you do `k%2*`, you can avoid the parens.

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.10](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 18 bytes

```
nd2%?.d2:~r[dN1+].
```

#### Explanation

```
n          Take input as integer (k)
d2%?.      Duplicate k and stop if it's even
d2:~       Duplicate k, then divide by 2 and negate to get first number
r          Put k on top
[    ].    Loop k times and then stop
 dN1+      Duplicate, output as integer, and increment
```

Answer (score 3):

## [DUP](https://esolangs.org/wiki/DUP), 31 bytes

```
[a:a;2/b:[b;_[$b;<][$1+]#][0]?]
```

<kbd>[Try it here.](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/dup.html)</kbd>

Anonymous lambda. Usage:

```
5[a:a;2/b:[b;_[$b;<][$1+]#][0]?]!
```

## Explanation

```
[                             ] {lambda}
 a:                             {store input to a}
   a;2/                         {divmod a by 2}
       b:                       {store quotient to b, top of stack is now remainder}
         [               ][ ]?  {conditional}
          b;_                   {if remainder is 1, get b and negate it}
             [    ][   ]#         {while loop}
              $b;<                {while top of stack is less than b}
                    $1+           {duplicate and increment}
                           0    {otherwise, leave falsy value}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
∷$½:N$ṡ∧
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%B7%24%C2%BD%3AN%24%E1%B9%A1%E2%88%A7&inputs=9&header=&footer=)

### Explanation

```
∷$½:N$ṡ∧
∷          Parity
 $         Swap (putting the input on top again)
  ½        Half
   :       Duplicate
    N      Negate
     $     Swap
      ṡ    Range from a to b
       ∧   Logical AND
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%BD%3AN%24%E1%B9%A1%E2%88%A7&inputs=9&header=&footer=) for 6 bytes no?

Comment: @lyxal The program must give a falsy output for all even numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
{_2md@,@f-*}
```

This is an anonymous function that pops an integer from the stack and pushes a digit array (odd base) or an empty array (even base) in return. Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%0A%20%20%7B_2md%40%2C%40f-*%7D%0A~p&input=3).

#### How it works

```
_          e# Copy the input (N).
 2md       e# Push N/2 and N%2.
    @      e# Rotate N on top of the stack.
     ,     e# Push [0 ... N-1].
      @    e# Rotate N/2 on top of the stack.
       f-  e# Subtract N/2 from each element of [0 ... N-1].
         * e# Repeat the resulting array N%2 times.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**.

```
U%2&&(X=-U/2+K o1-X
```

For odd inputs, returns a integer array of length `x`, centered at `0`; for even, returns 0. Rough JS translation:

```
output(U%2&&(X=-U/2+.5).range(1-X));
```

where `x.range(y)` creates a list of integers from `x` to `y`. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VSUyJiYoWD0tVS8yK70gbzEtWA==&input=Nw==)

---

In modern Japt, this is only 11 bytes:

```
u ©Uo-U/2-½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@1@qcGhlaL5uqL6R7qG9//9bAgA)

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer, can you please explain why? I'd like to know where I went wrong so I can fix it. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Perhaps they don't like the language? (I love the language, though I can see how others might not.)

Answer (score 2):

## O, 18

```
M(.e\2/.@{_}dmrr]p
```

[Live demo.](http://o-lang.herokuapp.com/link/code=M(.e%5C2%2F.%40%7B_%7Ddmrr%5Dp&input=3)

Comment: Is there a language for every capital letter in the English alphabet?!

Comment: They should also be listed in increasing order.

Comment: @MickeyT Fixed that at the cost of 5 bytes.

Comment: @Geobits Fixed that, too.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ [There are a couple available](http://blog.jadonfowler.xyz/2015/07/15/one-letter-languages.html)

Comment: @phase If anyone takes `Z`, I will be ticked. ;)

Comment: @ConorOBrien https://github.com/z-lang/z-lang and https://github.com/matt-auld/z-lang...

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, <s>27</s> 25 Bytes

I'm gonna golf this down tomorrow, but I really ought to go to bed now.

```
D2M)[&1]D1-i*}\[D2/NaO2+]
D                             Duplicate the input.
 2M)[&1]                      If the input is even (input%2=0) generate a new stack
                              and push 1 to it.
        D                     Duplicate the top value - if it wasn't even, this will be the input. Otherwise, it's one.
         1-                   Subtract one (to balance around zero)
           i*                 Additively invert
             }                Shift over an item in the stack - this ensures that
                              we have either the input or one on top.
              \[        ]     Repeat input times.
                D2/N          Duplicate the top item and print it out.
                    aO        Newline (I'm pretty sure this is valid separation)
                      2+      Add one to the top item of the stack.
```

Comment: "Final global var" that sounds intense

Comment: It _is_ intense.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ *intensity intensifies*

Answer (score 2):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 16 bytes <s>18</s>

```
x%2Þr(xØ)ßl-x/2)
```

Pretty simple. The special characters are actually just "abbreviations" for longer code sequences.

I still haven't made permalinks so you'll have to copy paste into the [interpreter](http://vihanserver.tk/p/TeaScript/)

#### Explanation

```
x%2 &&    // If x is NOT even return falsy, else...
r(x--)    // Range 0-input. Subtracts one from input
m(#       // Loop through range
  l-      // Current item in loop, minus...
    x/2   // input - 1, divided by two
)
```

<sub>This answer is non-competing</sub>

Comment: I should implement these special-char abbreviations into Japt. :) BTW, are you sure Ω is 1 byte?

Comment: @ETHproductions Aww :( forgot to check that before I implemented that. I'll fix that in the next commit

Comment: I hate that the Greek letters are 2-byte ;-;

Comment: Y'all are complaining? Feel glad you don't have to deal with 's unprintable chars. ;___;

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ lol, but looking at ESMin's source code, I recommend trying to keep special characters under 0xFF (255) to keep them 1-byte

Comment: @Vɪʜᴀɴ Nah, it's a nice challenge/quirk that keeps stuff interesting. Besides, unprintable chars look cool.

Comment: @ןnɟuɐɯɹɐןoɯ As long as you can actually see them. On my phone, not even your language's *name* is visible. :P

Comment: @Dennis It adds to the language's mysterious aura...

Answer (score 2):

### R, 30 bytes

```
function(n)(x=(1-n)/2*n%%2):-x
```

Roughly, `x:-x` returns the integers from `x` to `-x`, where I set `x` to `(1-n)/2`. I also use the modulo-2 factor `n%%2` in the definition of `x` to force `x` to zero when `n` is even, in which case, `0:0` returns `0` (falsey).

Answer (score 2):

## , 21 chars / 37 bytes

```
ô[…Ѧ(ï&1⅋ï‡)]ć⇀_-ï/2⸩
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=5&code=%C3%B4%5B%E2%80%A6%D1%A6%28%C3%AF%261%E2%85%8B%C3%AF%E2%80%A1%29%5D%C4%87%E2%87%80_-%C3%AF%2F2%E2%B8%A9)</kbd>

Here's a 20-char / 35-byte answer (non-competing, since the answer uses changes implemented after the question was asked):

```
ô(ï%2⅋ѨĶ(ï‡)ć⇀$-ï/2⸩
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=true&input=5&code=%C3%B4%28%C3%AF%252%E2%85%8B%D1%A8%C4%B6%28%C3%AF%E2%80%A1%29%C4%87%E2%87%80%24-%C3%AF%2F2%E2%B8%A9)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

## F#, 38 bytes

The falsey result is an empty list.

```
let O n=if n%2<1 then[]else[-n/2..n/2]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 6 (or 4?) [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
½k¥¿╤<
```

Outputs `0` as falsey output.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q3uxDSw/tfzR1ic3//6ZcJlyGXIZGXIbGAA)

If we're allowed to output `[0]` as falsey output, even though \$n=1\$ results in `[0]` as truthy output as well, this could be **4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)** instead:

```
¥*½╤
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///QUq1Dex9NXfL/vymXCZchl6ERl6ExAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
½       # Integer-divide the (implicit) input-integer by 2
 k      # Push the input-integer again
  ¥     # Modulo-2
   ¿    # If input%2 is truthy / 1 / odd:
    ╤   #  Pop the input//2 and push a list in the range [-input//2, input//2]
        # Else (it's falsey / 0 / even instead):
     <  #  Check if the (implicit) input is smaller than input//2, which is falsey / 0
        # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)

¥       # Modulo-2 on the (implicit) input-integer (1 if odd; 0 if even)
 *      # Multiply that by the (implicit) input-integer
  ½     # Integer-divide it by 2
   ╤    # Pop and push a list in the range [-(input%2*input//2), input%2*input//2]
        # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Is there a way in MathGolf to just multiply the two numbers after step 3 and then skip the if-else?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen That would result in outputs of `[0]` instead of `0` though. And since test case \$n=1\$ is truthy with output `[0]`, I can't use that same `[0]` as falsey value. I assume you meant something like [`½k¥*╤`](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q3uxDS7UeTV3y/78plwmXIZehEZehMQA)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, but I didn't expect that ```[0]``` would be truthy in MathGolf.

Comment: (after writing my *first ever* golfing [program](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q3uxDS7UeTV1yaL@h0f//plwmXIZchkZchsYA) to check that ```[0]``` is actually falsey) let's put it a different way: why does the output of n=1 need to be different from the falsey output of even n?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen No, `[0]` isn't truthy in MathGolf. But it is for this challenge for \$n=1\$. So if I also use `[0]` for all falsey results, how would you differentiate between a truthy `[0]` and falsey `[0]` result in this challange?

Comment: I just can't find anywhere where it says that the result of n=1 should be truthy...  (or even that one needs to discriminate at all between the output of n=1 and n=even; my answer currently gives exactly the same output (```0```) for both, and so do many of the others...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen You're right, it indeed doesn't. And I indeed saw a few answers that do the same, like the Japt answer. I've asked OP to verify, although since the challenge is from 5 years ago I have no idea if he'll respond. I'll edit my answer to include both versions for now.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 26 bytes

```r
a=scan();-(i=a%/%2*a%%2):i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9G2ODkxT0PTWlcj0zZRVV/VSCtRVdVI0yrzvynX//8A)

Integer-divide input by 2, and multiply by input modulo 2 (so it becomes zero if input is even).
Then output the range of integers from negative to positive of this value.

(for a fairer comparison with the previous (half-decade-old!) [R](https://www.r-project.org/) answer, the approach here would be [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##fctBCoAgEADAe/8QNIjK6hL4lmUzA0F2Qe3S57cf7HmYKhcWpJhuIIiFW2odOsOXKgd5Xoo9M1l0k80BzWz8iMZ4d2Yl2sUNiq6qelU3VXdVDzeI/A) as a function).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda x:x%2*[*range(-x//2+1,x//2+1)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPqfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkLVSCtaqygxLz1VQ7dCX99I21AHQmnG/i8oyswr0UjTAJGZeQWlJRqaQPDfFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 36 bytes

I have a feeling this can be shortened:

```
$,=$";$n=<>;print$n%2?-$n/2..$n/2:0;
```

Range treats floats as integers, so, e.g. 5/2 = 2.5 gets silently converted to 2.

(If formatting doesn't matter, then remove `$,=$";` for a total of 30 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

### Powershell, 49 bytes

```
param($a)$b=$a/2-.5;"[$(-$b..$b-join",")]"*($a%2)
```

Even numbers evaluated to `$false` since they provide an empty line output.

```
("[$(-$b..$b-join",")]"*($a%2))-eq $True ===> False
```

Odd numbers output the exact reference string.  You can save 4 more bytes (now `45`) by removing the `[]` from the output string.

```
PS> .\balanced.ps1 4


PS> .\balanced.ps1 5
[-2,-1,0,1,2]

PS> .\balanced.ps1 0


PS> .\balanced.ps1 1
[0]

PS>
```

### Powershell, 36 Bytes

```
param($a)$b=$a/2-.5;(-$b..$b)*($a%2)
```

This has the same falsey result but outputs the list of numbers separated by newlines:

```
PS> .\balanced-newline.ps1 4

PS> .\balanced-newline.ps1 1
0

PS> .\balanced-newline.ps1 5
-2
-1
0
1
2

PS>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 6, 25 bytes

The shortest lambda expression I could come up with that outputs a list rather than a range is:

```perl6
{$_%2&&|((1-$_)/2..$_/2)} # 25
```

Testing:

```perl6
for 0..10 -> $a {
  if {$_%2&&|((1-$_)/2..$_/2)}($a) -> $b {
    say "$a.fmt('%5s')  $b"
  } else {
    say "$a.fmt('%5s')  False"
  }
}
```

```perl6
    0  False
    1  0
    2  False
    3  -1 0 1
    4  False
    5  -2 -1 0 1 2
    6  False
    7  -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3
    8  False
    9  -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
   10  False
```

This takes advantage of the fact that Perl 6 treats the number `0` as a false value. If the output had to be exactly `False` you could replace `$_%2` with `$_!%%2`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Code:

```
È#¹;D(ŸR
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4gjwrk7RCjFuFI&input=Nw)

Explanation:

```
È#        # If input % 2 == 0, end the program
  ¹       # Push the first input from the register
   ;      # Halve, push input / 2 rounded down
    D     # Duplicate top of the stack
     (    # Negate
      Ÿ   # Inclusive range, pushes [a .. b]
       R  # Reverse the array
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>6</strike> 5 bytes

```
HŒRxḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/j6KSgioc7mv5bHt19uP1R05r/AA)

### Explanation

```
HŒRxḂ   Main monadic link
H       Halve
 ŒR     Balanced range
   x    Repeat
    Ḃ    parity of n
```

*-1 byte by finding out there's almost a builtin for this*

Answer (score 1):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 10 bytes

```
0?+0*:?\2__?+0-_?/2
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIwPyswKjo_XFwyX18_KzAtXz8vMiIsIlszM10iLDBd)

### Explanation

```
0     range
?         input
+       +
0         0
*   repeat
:     0 ≠
?         input
\       mod
2         2
_ map
_
?         item
+       +
0         0
-   -
_
?         input
/       /
2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 145 bytes

```
public class c{static void c(int n){for(int i=n/2*-1;i<=n/2;i++){if(n%2==0){System.out.print("false");break;}System.out.print(i);}}}
```

Explanation: Sorry, I know this is really long. I didn't see an answer for java so I decided to put one in. Let me know if I need to write the main function (Im not sure if thats the policy or not). Basically it divides the number by two and multiplies it by -1 for the lower bound and for the upper bound it just uses the number divided by two. I'm kind of new to this page so if I didn't format anything right then let me know. Also, I know that answers can be shortened with lambda functions but I don't know how to use them and Im not sure if Java supports them.

Here is a more readable version which is less golfed:

```
public class StackOverflow {
static void c(int n){
    for (int i = n/2*-1; i<=n/2; i++){
        if(n%2==0){
            System.out.print("false");
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The normal rule is that you need to write a program or function. In Java, a function will nearly always be shorter (especially as it lets you output via `return` – the return value is a legitimate form of output – rather than needin to use `System.out`, although in this case for `return` to work you'd need to store the partially constructed lists in a string). Recent Java does support lambdas, and they normally come out shorter than a "regular" function definition. (Also, why the leading whitespace?)

Comment: @ais523 The leading whitespace is just my own personal habit and I didn't include it in the byte count, I guess I should get rid of it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 50 bytes

```
<?=($n=$argv[1])&1?join(_,range(-$k=$n/2|0,$k)):0;
```

program, takes input from STDIN, prints `_` delimited list or `0`.

or

```
function f($n){return$n&1?range(-$k=$n/2|0,$k):0;}
```

function takes argument, returns array or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
->n{[*0-n/2..n/2]if n.odd?}
```

Creates an anonymous lambda function that will return the array of `n` numbers closest to 0 if n is odd, and returns nil (a falsey value in ruby) otherwise.

Ruby rounds its integer division towards -infinity, but `0-n/2` is shorter than `-n/2+1` (since the minus sign is there anyway), and because n is now considered positive, the rounding works in my favour.

#### Old Version (28 bytes)

```
->n{[*-n/2+1..n/2]if n.odd?}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 25 bytes

```
->n{n%2>0&&[*(-n/=2)..n]}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs `0` for even inputs.

```
u ©Uo-Uz
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=dSCpVW8tVXo&input=NQotUQ)

```
u ©Uo-Uz     :Implicit input of integer U
u            :Modulo 2
  ©          :Logical AND with
   Uo        :Range [0,U)
     -       :From each subtract
      Uz     :U floor divided by 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 15 bytes

```
~:&,{&2/-}%&2%*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v85KTadazUhft1ZVzUhV6/9/UwA)

```
~:&               # Assign n to &                    5                  4
   ,              # Make an array from 0 to n-1      [0 1 2 3 4]        [0 1 2 3]
    {    }%       # For every element in the array
     &2/-         # Subtract n/2                     [-2 -1 0 1 2]      [-2 -1 0 1]
           &2%*   # Multiply the array by n%2        [-2 -1 0 1 2]      []
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Nibbles](https://nibbles.golf), 5 bytes (10 nibbles)

```
^`%$~.`,@-
```

### Verbose version

```
^   # Repeat
  `% $ ~   # (input mod 2) times; save the value of input div 2
  .   # Map
    `, @   # Range from 0 to (input - 1)
    -   # argument - saved value
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,y=~n/2)=>y%1+!n?'':[++y,...f(n-1,y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQb9lBTEit7Y5z1Q8RD1LtyJBkqAi9@Ovde9/5mo@48@9sRJe1lBRATA63tE8Mfa48PWSo69dIlI21NoE03mScStIdOLiO3951RIxR5dBttZt@gE0CRix/)

Output empty string as false