# Mask an IP address and give its broadcast

Tags: code-golf, bitwise, networking

### Background

Inspired by [this Unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250740/replace-string-after-last-dot-in-bash) (and of course [my own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250808/34061)).

When an IP address is specified for an interface, it is often given in this dotted-decimal form:

```
a.b.c.d e.f.g.h
```

where `a.b.c.d` is the actual address and `e.f.g.h` is the netmask.

The netmask, when represented in binary, is basically a bunch of `1` bits followed by a bunch of `0` bits.  When the netmask is bitwise ANDed against the given IP address, result will be the *network* portion of the address, or simply the *network address*.  This will be programmed into the host's route table so that the host knows to send anything destined for this network out this interface.

The broadcast address for a network is derived by taking the network address (from above) and setting all the host-bits to 1.  The broadcast address is used to send to *all* addresses within the given network.

### Challenge

Given a dotted-decimal IP address and valid netmask as input, provide the network address and broadcast address as output, also in dotted-decimal format.

- Input must be address and mask as two strings in dotted-decimal format.  You may pass this as 2 separate strings, as list or array of 2 string elements or a single string with the address and mask separated by some sensible separator.
- Output format is subject to the same constraints as input format.

### Examples

```
Input                              Output

192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0          192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0          192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.255 255.255.255.0        192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
100.200.100.200 255.255.255.255    100.200.100.200 100.200.100.200
1.2.3.4 0.0.0.0                    0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
10.25.30.40 255.252.0.0            10.24.0.0 10.27.255.255
```

Comment: Will the netmask only have 255s and 0s?

Comment: @xnor The last example has `252` in it.

Comment: Shouldn't the last output be `10.24.0.0 10.27.255.255`?

Comment: @xnor no, the net masks can be any length from 0 to 32

Comment: @Pietu1998 no, 255.252.0.0 is a valid mask. In binary it is 11111111.11111100.00000000.00000000

Comment: Yeah, but I mean that the given broadcast output is `00001010000110110000000000000000` (the last bits are not 1's).

Comment: @Pietu1998 Oh yeah - sorry - its fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

```js
(a,m)=>a.split`.`.map((n,i)=>(v=m[i],m[i]=n&v|v^255,n&v),m=m.split`.`).join`.`+" "+m.join`.`
```

### Explanation

```js
(a,m)=>
  a.split`.`
  .map((n,i)=>(
      v=m[i],
      m[i]=n&v|v^255,
      n&v
    ),
    m=m.split`.`
  ).join`.`
  +" "+m.join`.`
```

### Test

```js
var solution = (a,m)=>a.split`.`.map((n,i)=>(v=m[i],m[i]=n&v|v^255,n&v),m=m.split`.`).join`.`+" "+m.join`.`
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" value="10.25.30.40 255.252.0.0" />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution.apply(null,input.value.split` `)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/4.0.0), 47 bytes

This answer uses [current version (4.0.0)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/4.0.0) of the language.

```
'%i.%i.%i.%i't32whh2:"j'\d+'XXU]tbZ&tb255Z~+hYD
```

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > '%i.%i.%i.%i't32whh2:"j'\d+'XXU]tbZ&tb255Z~+hYD
 > 
> 192.168.0.1
> 255.255.255.0
192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
```

#### Explanation

```
'%i.%i.%i.%i't32whh      % format string: '%i.%i.%i.%i %i.%i.%i.%i'
2:"                      % for loop: do this twice
    j'\d+'XXU            % input string and parse into 4-vector with the numbers
]                        % end
tbZ&                     % compute network address
tb255Z~+                 % compute broadcast address
hYD                      % concatenate into 8-vector and apply format string
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, [<s>44</s>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/rolling-the-dice/66463#comment162348_66463) 42 bytes

```
LisMcb\.256Lj\..[04jb256'J.&yzKyw'+JxKt^2 32
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lj%5C..%5B04jb256yJ.%26FAmisMcd%5C.256Qy%2BJxHt%5E2%2032&input=%5B%2210.25.30.40%22%2C+%22255.252.0.0%22%5D&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Lj%5C..%5B04jb256yJ.%26FAmisMcd%5C.256Qy%2BJxHt%5E2%2032&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%22192.168.0.1%22%2C+%22255.255.255.0%22%5D%0A%5B%22192.168.0.0%22%2C+%22255.255.255.0%22%5D%0A%5B%22192.168.0.255%22%2C+%22255.255.255.0%22%5D%0A%5B%22100.200.100.200%22%2C+%22255.255.255.255%22%5D%0A%5B%221.2.3.4%22%2C+%220.0.0.0%22%5D%0A%5B%2210.25.30.40%22%2C+%22255.252.0.0%22%5D&debug=0&input_size=1)

Expects the input as an array, like `["10.25.30.40", "255.252.0.0"]`.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 126 bytes

With input in $n:

```php
preg_filter(~Ð×£ÔÖÐ,~Û¤¢Â×ÛÎÖÑ×ÛÔÔÁÌÀ×ÛÑÂ×ÛÂÛÁÊÀÝÑÝÅÝÝÖÑ×Û¤ÛÒÊ¢ÙÛÎÖÖÑ×ÛÑÂÛÑ×Û¤ÛÒÊ¢ÍÊÊÙÛÎÖÖÅÝÝÖ,$n);echo"$c $b";
```

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 7072 6567 5f66 696c 7465 7228 7ed0 d7a3  preg_filter(~...
0000010: 9bd4 d6d0 9a2c 7edb 9ea4 a2c2 d7db ced6  .....,~.........
0000020: d1d7 db96 d4d4 c1cc c0d7 db9c d1c2 d7db  ................
0000030: 8bc2 db96 c1ca c0dd d1dd c5dd ddd6 d1d7  ................
0000040: db9e a4db 96d2 caa2 d9db ced6 d6d1 d7db  ................
0000050: 9dd1 c2db 8bd1 d7db 9ea4 db96 d2ca a283  ................
0000060: cdca cad9 81db ced6 d6c5 dddd d62c 246e  .............,$n
0000070: 293b 6563 686f 2224 6320 2462 223b       );echo"$c $b";
```

And a more readable version:

```php
preg_filter( /* PCRE regex on input */
    '/(\d+)/e', /* match all digits, execute the code for each one */
    '$a[]=($1) /* push the matched value to the array $a */
        .($i++>3 /* if we're at the 5th or higher digit */
            ?($c.=($t=$i>5?".":"").($a[$i-5]&$1)) /* append to $c bitwise AND-ed number */
                .($b.=$t.($a[$i-5]|255&~$1)) /* append to $b the broadcast address */
            :"")',
    $n);
echo"$c $b"; /* output $c and $b */
```

`preg_filter` requires a single statement in the replacement pattern when using the `e` flag, so I 'append' the result of the calculations to the 5th and higher values of $a, because those are never reused.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, <s>90</s> 85 bytes

*includes +6 for `-pF/\D/`*

```
for(0..3){push@a,$F[$_]&1*($y=$F[$_+4]);push@b,$F[$_]|~$y&255}$"='.';$_="@a @b"
```

Usage:

```
echo "192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0" | perl -pF/\\D/ file.pl
```

More readable:

```
for(0..3) {
    push @a, $F[$_] & 1*($y=$F[$_+4]);  # calc/add network address 'byte'
    push @b, $F[$_] | ~$y & 255         # calc/add broadcast address 'byte'
}
$"='.';                                 # set $LIST_SEPARATOR
$_="@a @b"                              # set output to network address and broadcast
```

The `-F/\D/` splits the input on non-digits and stores it in `@F`.

Answer (score 0):

## Factor, 103 bytes

```
[ [ ipv4-aton ] bi@ 2dup bitand -rot dup bit-count 32 - abs on-bits pick bitor 2nip [ ipv4-ntoa ] bi@ ]
```

Nice.

Ungolfed:

```
: mask-and-broadcast ( ip mask -- netaddr broadcast )
  [ ipv4-aton ] bi@ 2dup bitand -rot dup bit-count 32 - abs on-bits pick bitor 2nip
  [ ipv4-ntoa ] bi@ ;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 74 bytes

```php
<?=long2ip($i=ip2long($argv[1])&$m=ip2long($argv[2])),' ',long2ip($i|~$m);
```

As a standalone, input is via command line:

```php
$ php ip.php 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42Jz8v3SizQEMl0zazwAjE01BJLEovizaM1VRTyUUTNIrV1NRRV1DXQWirqVPJ1bT@//@/oaWRnqGZhZ6BnuF/I1NTPRg2AAA)

Or as a function, **80 bytes**:

```php
function($a,$b){return[long2ip($i=ip2long($a)&$m=ip2long($b)),long2ip($i|~$m)];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZJda4MwFIavm19xkDANhDSmdh84t6vBLgbrvZVhxU7HqkHtVdf9dXdSbe0cg10sIcl7Di9PziHRmW5v73WmgeYagna9LZImLwuHxpyu2K5Km21VhO9l8apy7dA8yLUyERrYBd0M4YoxPtg@PumGRf6@9QmhTVo3NQQQkkkItnujhHt5LaRwbQ62ms/FcUkbIg7dmE67c7DLM43uEUz@Jwwzv@P@CJOocfXnGGduMMAT7Lt9HHdIocRMeAYlxWGetTiMI7L3wOjavjqUYiaFh5X1hamfxKE6obyuUVRXJ1SEz7suqzROMgf6d45rVMBgRyZpkpXwVuaFY4HFMc04WMsmuDPRIW8DdkPNl2lCGXHc3Qg/EiweFy8Pz0/@hOxJ@wU)

***Ungolfed***

```php
function ip( $a, $b ) {
    $i = ip2long( $a );          // string IP to 32 bit int
    $m = ip2long( $b );          // string netmask to 32 bit int
    $n = $i & $m;                // network is bitwise AND of IP and netmask
    $c = $i | ~$m;               // broadcast is bitwise OR of IP and inverse netmask
    return [ long2ip( $n ), long2ip( $c ) ];
}
```

PHP has nice (albeit with long function names) built-ins to handle IPv4 dotted-string to binary and back.

***Output***

```php
192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0   => 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0   => 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
192.168.0.255 255.255.255.0 => 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.255
100.200.100.200 255.255.255.255 => 100.200.100.200 100.200.100.200
1.2.3.4 0.0.0.0 => 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
10.25.30.40 255.252.0.0 => 10.24.0.0 10.27.255.255
```