# Zigzag a string

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

A zigzag scan is a method of encoding 2D information in one dimension:

[image: Zigzag scan]

Write a function or program that, given a one-dimensional string of printable ASCII characters, will reverse the zigzag scan to arrange its characters into a square.

For example, given the input string `ABeIfCDgJmnKhLop`, your program should return:

```
ABCD
efgh
IJKL
mnop
```

Here it is with the zigzag illustrated. The green line shows the order of the original characters, starting at the top left:

[image: ABCD\nefgh\nIJKL\nmnop]

The side length  of the output (i.e. the number of rows and columns) for an input string of length  must equal ⌈√̅⌉ (`ceil(sqrt(n))`). The zigzag pattern is slightly different for even and odd values of . Note how to upper right corner of the zigzag in the below example ( = 5) differs from the above ( = 4).

Given the string `Woamnlfgasa d gAeMrtouz`, your output should be:

```
Wolfg
ang A
madeu
s Moz
art
```

That is:

[image: Wolfg\nang A\nmadeu\ns Moz\nart]

### Winning

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The solution with the fewest bytes win.

### Rules

Input must be taken as a single string or list of characters. It may not have any extra whitespace, but for a single trailing newline. The input (sans newline) will have length 1 ≤  ≤ 4,096.

Output must be a string with multiple lines, a list of strings, or a list of lists of characters. Trailing whitespace (any amount) on each line is allowed but optional, as is a single trailing newline.

Standard loopholes are forbidden.

### Test cases

The below test cases are formatted as:

> ```
> Input
>
> Output
> ...
> ```

```
$

$
```

```
PPCG

PP
CG
```

```
foobarbaz

for
oab
baz
```

```
Ooo...    ...ooO

Oo. 
o. .
. .o
 .oO
```

```
OOo.oOOo.oOo.oOo.oOOo.oOO

OOOOO
ooooo
.....
ooooo
OOOOO
```

```
PrmPmogiusC znragzaooldnl edef   G

Progra 
mming  
Puzzle 
s and  
Code G 
olf
```

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Thuin v
eqcwfoe
 koo ry
 rxs z 
b ptad
jmhlo
ue g
```

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14532/11261)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150117/boustrophedonise)

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75587/8478) (The opposite conversion and on matrices instead of strings.)

Comment: @MartinEnder Oh for heaven's sake. I searched for ages. Apparently the keyword I was missing was "zigzagify." In fact, [this other challenge of yours](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75588/reconstruct-a-zigzagified-matrix) (the reverse operation) is pretty much a duplicate. I really wish this had come up in the sandbox.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot that I did both directions of this conversion... in that case yes, that's a very close match.

Comment: I think I need to just start posting very, very rough drafts in the sandbox, and then harassing people in chat non-stop to actually read them before I put so much work into them.

Comment: Why are people nominating this for reopening? This is an exact duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I’m not sure, but this challenge appeals to me over the other one because the languages I like to golf in (Ruby, sed) have string manipulation capabilities that just make this one more fun.