# Determine the color of a chess square

Tags: code-golf, chess

Your challenge is to write a program that outputs the color of a given square from the chessboard. This is how a chessboard looks:

[image]

You can see that the square **a1** is dark, and **h1** is a light square. Your program needs to output `dark` or `light`, when given a square. Some examples:

```
STDIN:  b1
STDOUT: light

STDIN:  g6
STDOUT: light

STDIN:  d4
STDOUT: dark
```

The rules:

- You need to provide a full program that uses STDIN and uses STDOUT to output `dark` or `light`.
- Assume that the input is always valid (`[a-h][1-8]`)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest amount of bytes wins!

## Scoreboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=63772,OVERRIDE_USER=8478;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Why hasn't anyone tried <>^Fish?

Comment: shortest amount of bytes total or in a given language?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## [GS2](https://github.com/nooodl/gs2), <s>17</s> 15 bytes

```
de♦dark•light♠5
```

The source code uses the [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Characters) encoding. [Try it online!](http://gs2.tryitonline.net/#code=ZGXimaZkYXJr4oCibGlnaHTimaA1&input=YjE)

#### Verification

```
$ xxd -r -ps <<< 6465046461726b076c696768740635 > chess.gs2
$ wc -c chess.gs2 
15 chess.gs2
$ gs2 chess.gs2 <<< b1
light
```

#### How it works

```
d               Add the code points of the input characters.
 e              Compute the sum's parity.
  ♦             Begin a string literal.
   dark
       •        String separator.
        light
             ♠  End the string literal; push as an array of strings.
              5 Select the element that corresponds to the parity.
```

Comment: That's amazing! With 9 unavoidable bytes, 3 byte outgolfing Pyth and CJam is amazing.

Comment: Holy cow, guys, GS2 is the new Pyth! Somebody figure it out how to use it well before Denni...never mind.

Comment: Did you just steal GS2's powerful string literal system to Jelly?

Answer (score 64):

## Python 2, <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```
print'ldiagrhkt'[int(input(),35)%2::2]
```

*3 bytes thanks to Mego for string interlacing*

Takes input like `"g6"`. That's light and dark intertwined.

Comment: That's just gorgeous with the string interlacing.

Comment: I'd actually say that `int(input(),35)` is the brilliant part. I thought of the string interlacing, but your input method saves the most bytes.

Comment: +1 if you un-golf and explain your answer, please

Answer (score 25):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
,},";h;g;;d/;k;-'2{=%<i;\@;trl;a
```

Unfolded and with annotated execution paths:

[image]
<sup>Diagram generated with [Timwi's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi) amazing [HexagonyColorer](https://github.com/Timwi/HexagonyColorer).</sup>

The purple path is the initial path which reads two characters, computes their difference and takes it modulo 2. The `<` then acts as a branch, where the dark grey path (result `1`) prints `dark` and light grey path (result `0`) prints `light`.

As for how I compute the difference and modulo, here is a diagram of the memory grid (with values taken for the input `a1`):

[image]
<sup>Diagram generated with [Timwi's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/668/timwi) even more amazing [Esoteric IDE](https://bitbucket.org/Timwi/esoteric-ide) (which has a visual debugger for Hexagony).</sup>

The memory pointer starts on the edge labelled *row*, where we read the character. `}` moves to the edge labelled *col*, where we read the digit. `"` moves to the edge labelled *diff* where `-` computes the difference of the two. `'` moves to the unlabelled cell where we put the `2`, and `{=` moves to the cell labelled *mod* where we compute the modulo with `%`.

This might be golfable by a few bytes by reusing some of the `;`, but I doubt it can be golfed by much, certainly not down to side-length 3.

Comment: Ooh, pretty colors!

Comment: This language is new to me but I am amazed at your ability to come up with something more contrived than I thought possible

Comment: I really don't get all these golf languages.

Comment: @codeSwift4Life Hexagony is far from being a golfing language. For trivial tasks like this it might be reasonably competitive, because it has single-character commands, but that is more a necessity [shared by many other 2D languages](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Category:Two-dimensional_languages), including Befunge, Piet, ><>. Any nontrivial task will require very large amounts of code and complicated programs, due to Hexagony's weird memory model. It is in no way meant to be a concise language, but rather an exotic and weird one, exploring programming on hexagonal grids.

Comment: @qwr I thought being contrived was the point of esolangs. ;)

Comment: Wow...I never bothered trying to figure out how the hexagonal memory model worked, but your example (paired with the diagram) just snapped into place in my brain. Wish there were somewhere I could +1 the language!

Comment: @ETHproductions Well, there's [this meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6997/8478) and you can star it on GitHub if you want. :P

Answer (score 20):

### CJam, 18 bytes

```
r:-)"lightdark"5/=
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%3A-)%22lightdark%225%2F%3D&input=b1)

#### Dissection

```
r               e# Read a token of input
:-              e# Fold -, giving the difference between the two codepoints
)               e# Increment, changing the parity so that a1 is odd
"lightdark"5/   e# Split the string to get an array ["light" "dark"]
=               e# Index with wrapping, so even => "light" and odd => "dark"
```

Comment: your code is smiling `:-)`

Comment: I did consider the equally effective `:^)`

Comment: Please can you explain how this works.

Comment: @Fogmeister, added explanation.

Answer (score 17):

## sed, 37

```
s/[1357aceg]//g
/^.$/{clight
q}
cdark
```

#### Explanation

`s/[1357aceg]//g` removes all odd-indexed coordinates.  The resulting pattern buffer then has length of 1 for "light" or length of 0 or 2 for "dark".  `/^.$/` matches the 1-length patterns, `c`hanges the pattern to "light" and `q`uits.  Otherwise the pattern is `c`hanged to "dark".

Comment: The `q` is redundant, and you can check for dark first instead with `/../`, https://tio.run/##K05N@f@/WD/a0NjUPDE5NT1WXz@dS19PTz85JbEomys5JzM9o@T//yRDrnQzrhQTAA

Answer (score 14):

## ShadyAsFuck, 91 bytes / BrainFuck, 181 bytes

My first real BrainFuck program, thank Mego for the help and for pointing me to the algorithm archive. (That means I didn't really do it on my own, but copied some existing algorithms. Still an experience=)

```
NKnmWs3mzhe5aAh=heLLp5uR3WPPPPagPPPPsuYnRsuYgGWRzPPPPlMlk_PPPPPP4LS5uBYR2MkPPPPPPPP_MMMkLG]
```

This is of course the translation from my brainfuck answers:

```
,>,[<+>-]++<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>[-]>>[-]++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]<[<+>>+<-]<[>+<-]+>>[>++++++++.---.--.+.++++++++++++.<<<->>[-]]<<[>>>.---.+++++++++++++++++.-------.<<<-]
```

Developed using [this interpreter/debugger](http://www.iamcal.com/misc/bf_debug/).

I stole two code snippets for `divmod` and `if/else` from [here.](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms) (Thanks to @Mego!)

```
,>,               read input
[<+>-]            add
++<               set second cell to 2
```

Now we have the cells config `>sum 2` we now perform the divmod algorithm:

```
[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>
[-]>
```

The output of the divmod looks like this `0 d-n%d >n%d n/d` but we zeroed the `d-n%d` and are zeroing the next cell too:

```
>[-]
```

Fill one cell up to the value `100` for easier outputting:

```
++++++++++[>++++++++++<-]<
```

Now the configuration is `>cond 0 100` and for applying the `if/else` algorithm we need two temp variables, so we choose the configuration `temp0 >c temp1 100`

```
c[<temp0+>>temp1+<c-]<temp0[>c+<temp0-]+
>>temp1[
 #>++++++++.---.--.+.++++++++++++.<         outputs light
 <<temp0-
>>temp1[-]]
<<temp0[
 #>>>.---.+++++++++++++++++.-------.<<<     outputs dark
temp0-]
```

Answer (score 13):

### Python 2, 45 bytes

```python
print'dlairgkh t'[sum(map(ord,input()))%2::2]
```

Takes input like `"a1"`. [Try it online](http://ideone.com/1blfkH)

Comment: This wouldn't work in Python 3 due to the lack of parens for the print.

Comment: Can't test right now but something like `"ldiagrhgt"[expression::2]` should work while saving a byte or two

Answer (score 12):

### [Seriously](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 19 bytes

```
"dark""light"2,O+%I
```

Takes input like `"a1"`

[Try it online](http://seriouslylang.herokuapp.com/link/code=226461726b22226c6967687422322c4f2b2549&input=%22a1%22) (you will have to manually enter the input; the permalinks don't like quotes)

Comment: Online link ded..

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
@c2"lightdark"iz35
```

Interpret the input as a base 35 number, chop `lightdark` in half, print.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 45 bytes

```
alert(parseInt(prompt(),35)%2?"dark":"light")
```

Comment: way to go to use a radix! +1 FTW...

Comment: Is there a particular reason `alert` and `prompt` have to be the way that `STDOUT` and `STDIN` are interpreted for JavaScript? If a normal arrow function is allowed, then it would just be: `x=>parseInt(x,35)%2?"dark":"light"`

Comment: @SteveBennett the challenge asks for a full program so a function wouldn't be allowed as that requires separate code to execute it.

Comment: But your code isn't a "full program" either because it would need to be embedded within an HTML page running in a browser.  Seems like kind of a dodgy requirement.

Answer (score 10):

## Turing Machine Code, 235 bytes

Using the rule table syntax defined [here.](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html)

```
0 a _ r 1
0 c _ r 1
0 e _ r 1
0 g _ r 1
0 * _ r 2
1 2 _ r 3
1 4 _ r 3
1 6 _ r 3
1 8 _ r 3
2 1 _ r 3
2 3 _ r 3
2 5 _ r 3
2 7 _ r 3
* * _ r 4
3 _ l r A
A _ i r B
B _ g r C
C _ h r D
D _ t r halt
4 _ d r E
E _ a r F
F _ r r G
G _ k r halt
```

Comment: This is possibly the most amazing thing I have ever seen lol

Answer (score 9):

## TI-BASIC, 66 bytes

Tested on a TI-84+ calculator.

```
Input Str1
"light
If inString("bdfh",sub(Str1,1,1)) xor fPart(.5expr(sub(Str1,2,1
"dark
Ans
```

Here's a more interesting variation on the third line, which sadly is exactly the same size:

```
Input Str1
"dark
If variance(not(seq(inString("bdfh2468",sub(Str1,X,1)),X,1,2
"light
Ans
```

You'd think TI-BASIC would be decent at this challenge, since it involves modulo 2. It's not; these solutions seem to be the shortest possible.

We spend a lot of bytes to get both characters in the string, but what really costs is the thirteen two-byte lowercase letters.

Answer (score 8):

### [Befunge-93](http://www.esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), <s>39</s> <s>37</s> <s>33</s> 31 bytes

All credit to [**Linus**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46756/linus) who [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63772/determine-the-color-of-a-chess-square/63791?noredirect=1#comment154160_63791) this 31-byte solution:

```
<>:#,_@  v%2-~~
"^"light"_"krad
```

Test it using [this interpreter](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html).

#### Explanation

```
<        v%2-~~
```

The `<` at the beginning sends the instruction pointer to the left, where it wraps around to the right. It then reads in two characters from input as ASCII, subtracts them, and does a modulo by 2. As `a` and `1` are both odd (in terms of ASCII code), this works. The `v` redirects the instruction pointer downward...

```
"^"light"_"krad
```

...onto the `_`, which sends the instruction pointer to the left if the top of stack is 0 and to the right otherwise. The characters of "light" or "dark", respectively, are pushed onto the stack in reverse order. Both paths hit the `^` at the left, which sends the instruction pointer upward...

```
 >:#,_@
```

...to the output segment. `:` duplicates the top of stack, `#` jumps over the `,` and onto the `_`, which sends the instruction pointer to the right if the top of stack is 0 and left otherwise. When the stack is empty, the top of stack (after `:`) is 0, so the instruction pointer hits the `@` which stops execution. Otherwise, it hits the `,`, which outputs the top of stack as a character, and then the `#` jumps it over the `:` and onto the `>`, which starts the process again.

Comment: save a byte using `rad"v>"k` without a space?

Comment: @Linus: "The space is necessary because otherwise the output would be `dar k`." Try it in the linked online interpreter.

Comment: Your right. Anyway, I was going to do this in befunge but I can only get 2 bytes under you... `<>:#,_@  v%2-~~\n"^"light"_"krad`, fix the newline.

Comment: @Linus: That's brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesHolderness, No hard feelings. You're right to point out this doesn't work in the original Befunge-93 interpreter, [the actual spec](http://catseye.tc/view/befunge-93/doc/Befunge-93.markdown) is for an 80x25 torus. You might want to post your version as it's own answer and explain the difference. I think at least that would be more practical than debating year-old hobby code with me.

Answer (score 7):

## Java, <s>157</s> <s>127</s> 124 bytes

```
interface L{static void main(String[]a){System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextInt(35)%2>0?"dark":"light");}}
```

Comment: You could use an interface like this : `interface i{static void main` since the everything in an interface is public by default

Answer (score 7):

## C, 55 bytes

```c
s;main(){puts(strtol(gets(&s),0,19)&1?"light":"dark");}
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/Xvn8ts)

Thanks DigitalTrauma for lots of golfing tips

Comment: I think you have an extra `(` after `puts`

Comment: This for 55: `s;main(){puts(strtol(gets(&s),0,19)&1?"light":"dark");}`.  Assumes that the integer width is big enough to hold 3 chars of string.  You should also be able to do `main(s){puts(strtol(gets(&s),0,19)&1?"light":"dark");}` for 54, though for some reason gets() is returning garbage is `s` if not global, so it segfaults.

Comment: oh wow, base-19. clever.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

**Japt** is a shortened version of **Ja**vaScri**pt**. [Interpreter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62685/42545)

```
Un19 %2?"dark":"light"
```

#### How it works

```
          // Implicit: U = input string
Un19      // Convert U from a base 19 number to decimal.
%2        // Take its modulo by 2.
?"dark"   // If this is 1, return "dark".
:"light"  // Else, return "light".
          // Implicit: output last expression
```

Using the new version 0.1.3 (released Nov 22), this becomes **17 bytes**, shorter than all but GS2:

```
Un19 %2?`»rk:¦ght
```

Or, alternatively, a magic formula: (26 bytes)

```
Un19 %2*22189769+437108 sH
Un19 %2                    // Convert input to base 19 and modulo by 2.
       *22189769+437108    // Where the magic happens (top secret)
                        sH // Convert to a base 32 string.
```

Answer (score 7):

## C, 49 bytes

```
main(c){gets(&c);puts(c+c/256&1?"light":"dark");}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't compile.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I had fiddled with something else. [The output is wrong, though](https://bpaste.net/raw/8e360ff0fc68). I think you meant to do `gets(&c)%256+c/256`?

Comment: Oh, good catch. Though at this point, my solution is strictly worse than yours as we're using the same technique. Looks like I have plenty to learn.

Comment: It turns out that the wrong output was caused by the return value of `gets(&c)`. I have updated my submission accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

## [TeaScript](https://github.com/vihanb/TeaScript), 23 [bytes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)

```
®x,35)%2?"dark":"light"
```

Unfortunately the strings `dark` and `light` can't be compressed.

Comment: Hehe, [Japt is shorter for once](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63793/42545) ;) +1 though, the JS compression techniques are great! I may add them into Japt after revamping the interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

## [BotEngine](http://esolangs.org/wiki/BotEngine), <s>165</s> 14x11=154

```
v acegbdfh
>ISSSSSSSS
 v<<<<>v<<P
vS1   vS2ke
vS3   vS4re
vS5   vS6ae
vS7   vS8de
>     >   ^
>     >  v
^S2   ^S1el
^S4   ^S3ei
^S6  P^S5eg
^S8 te^S7eh
     ^   <
```

Here it is with the different path segments highlighted:

[image]

(Any non-space characters not highlighted serve as arguments for the `e` and `S` instructions- each of these instructions uses the symbol to the left (relative to the bot's direction of travel) as its argument)

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, *<s>[striked out 44](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/very-simple-triangles/48101#comment113015_48101...)</s>* 36 bytes

```
puts %w[light dark][gets.to_i(19)%2]
```

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing `puts ` with `$><<` (no space).

Comment: @Mauris I know, but i like my terminating newline

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by changing `puts` for `p`

Answer (score 6):

## , 26 chars / 34 bytes

```
ô(שǀ(ï,ḣ)%2?`dark`:`light”
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter.html?eval=false&input=&code=%E2%86%BA%3B%E1%B8%80%3C%E1%B9%A5%3B%E1%B8%80%E2%A7%BA%29%E1%B5%96%E1%B8%80)</kbd>

Comment: I wouldn't call it "compression" if it takes *more* bytes :P

Comment: I'm more worried about chars than bytes at this point. I've entirely given up on trying to golf down byte count in ...

Comment: We always score by bytes, and while it's often interesting to optimize for a secondary objective, remember that the fewest bytes always wins.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. I'm not really aiming for winning as much though.

Answer (score 6):

### Clojure, 63 bytes

```
(pr (['light 'dark] (mod (Integer/parseInt (read-line) 35) 2)))
```

- We read in a line from stdin with (read-line)
- Then parse the string into an integer value in base 35 using a call to a JVM method
- Taking mod of the result 2 tells us if it is even or odd
- Use the result returned from the modulo function as an index to the sequence and print it

I save a worthy 2 bytes by quoting out "light" and "dark" with a single quote so that Clojure takes it as a literal, as opposed to wrapping each word in a pair of quotation marks. I also save a few bytes by using pr rather than println.

[Some info on quoting in Clojure](https://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2012/05/22/quoting-without-confusion.html)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! This is a nice first answer. :) I'm not too familiar with Clojure; would you mind adding an explanation?

Comment: Absolutely! There you go. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 5):

## C, 46 bytes

```
main(c){gets(&c);puts(c%37%2?"light":"dark");}
```

Expects an environment where `int`s are stored little-endian, and are at least two bytes.

### Explanation

`c` is `argc`, so initially it contains `01 00 00 00`. `gets` will read two chars, say `a (0x61)` and `1 (0x31)`, and store them in `c`, which is now

```
61 31 00 00
```

representing the number 0x3161, or 12641.

Essentially, in this problem, given `c = x + 256*y`, we want to compute `(x + y) mod 2`, and print a string accordingly. To do this, I could have written `c % 255 % 2`, as then

```
  (x + 256 * y) % 255 % 2
= (x % 255 + y % 255) % 2      since 256 ≡ 1 (mod 255)
= (x + y) % 2                  since 0 < x, y < 255
```

However, `37` also works:

```
  (x + 256 * y) % 37 % 2
= (x % 37 - 3 * (y % 37)) % 2  since 256 ≡ -3 (mod 37)
```

`x` is in the range 49-57 inclusive (digits 1-8), so `x % 37 == x - 37`.

`y` is in the range 97-104 inclusive (lowercase a-h), so `y % 37 == y - 74`.

This means we can simplify to

```
= (x - 3 * y + 185) % 2
= (x + y + 1) % 2              since -3 ≡ 185 ≡ 1 (mod 2)
```

and simply flip the strings to correct for the parity.

Answer (score 5):

## [Beam](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Beam), 127 bytes

```
rSr>`+v
   ^  )
n(`)nS<
    >L'''''>`+++++)S>`+++)@---@'''>`+++++)++@-------@H
>L'''''>`+++)S>`++++++)+++@---@--@+@'''>`++++)@H
```

An explanation
[image]
Light blue - read a character from input into beam, save the beam value into the store, read a character from input into beam.

Dark blue - Adds store to beam by decrementing store to 0 while incrementing the beam

Light green - An even odd testing construct.  The loop will exit to the left if the beam is even or the right if odd.

Dark green - Outputs dark

Tan - Outputs light

Answer (score 5):

## [O](https://github.com/phase/o), <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
i#2%"light'dark"?
```

This does what it is required to do, with no additional benefits.

Answer (score 4):

## Matlab, 51 bytes

I do not think this needs any explanation=)

```
a={'light','dark'};disp(a(2-mod(sum(input('')),2)))
```

Answer (score 4):

### [Minkolang 0.12](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), <s>28</s> 24 bytes

```
on+2%t"dark"t"light"t$O.
```

[Try it here.](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/old?code=on%2B2%25t%22dark%22t%22light%22t%24O%2E&input=c6)

#### Explanation

```
o                   Take character from input
n                   Take integer from input
+                   Add
2%                  Modulo by 2
t      t       t    Ternary; runs first half if top of stack is 0, second half otherwise
 "dark" "light"     Pushes the string "dark" or "light", depending.
$O.                 Output the whole stack as characters and stop.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth), <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 42 bytes

*Thanks to Sp3000 for saving two bytes.*

```
-,"
#
%0:::8.5.3.4.116.@
1
00.97.114.107.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/labyrinth#@6@ro8SlzKVqYGVlZaFnqmesZ6JnaGim58BlyGVgoGdpDuQBRQzM9Rz@/083AwA)

#### Explanation

The beginning of the code is a funny dead end. Remember that Labyrinth assumes an infinite number of zeroes when it requires operands at the bottom of the stack. The code starts one the `-` going right, which tries to subtract two numbers, so the stack becomes:

```
[ ... 0 ]
```

Then `,` reads the first character, `a` say:

```
[ ... 0 97 ]
```

The `"` is a no-op, but this is also a dead-end so the instruction pointer turns around and starts going to the left. Then `` ` `` reads the other character, `2` say:

```
[ ... 0 97 50 ]
```

This time, `-` subtracts those two numbers:

```
[ ... 0 47 ]
```

The IP now follows the bend of the "corridor". The `#` gets the stack depth, ignoring the implicit zeroes, which conveniently happens to be `2`:

```
[ ... 0 47 2 ]
```

And `%` computes the modulo:

```
[ ... 0 1 ]
```

At this point, the IP is at a junction. If the top of the stack is zero, it will move straight ahead, where `100.97.114.107.@` prints `dark`. But if the top of the stack is non-zero (specifically, `1`), it will move to the right, where `0:::8.5.3.4.116.@` prints `light` (note that we can omit the leading `1`, because there is already a `1` on the stack, and we can save on the repeated `10` in `108`, `105`, `103`, `104` by making a few copies of the `10` when we first get there).

Answer (score 4):

### [Brian & Chuck](https://github.com/mbuettner/brian-chuck), 66 bytes

```
,>,_{->-?+{-_?>}<?light{-_?>}>>?dark?
II{<?}<<<?{<{<<<?_>.>.>.>.>.
```

Probably still golfable, but I think I'd need another approach.

#### Explanation

`,>,` reads input into Chuck, replacing the two `I`s. Next is the following part of the code:

```
   _{->-?
  {<?
```

which decrements both input elements until the latter (i.e. the digit) reaches zero. This stops Brian's `?` from passing control to Chuck, continuing on.

The next `+` increments the zeroed digit to a 1 so that following uses of `{` don't get caught on it. At this point, the first cell of Chuck's tape has the difference of the two code points, so now we need to take the code point modulo 2. This is done with the following parts:

```
          A            B            C
          {-_?>}<?     {-_?>}>>?    ?
     }<<<?{<{<<<?
```

I've labelled the three parts on Brian's tape to make things easier to explain. The `{-` in parts A and B decrement the first cell on Chuck's tape, and the following `?` checks if it's zero. If it's not, then control is passed, and we execute `}<<<?`. For part A, this moves us to part B. For part B, this moves us to part C, which immediately passes control and we execute `{<{<<<?`, sending us back to part A. Thus the effect is that we alternate between parts A and B, in a state machine-like way.

Now whether the first cell was zeroed while we were in part A or part B determines what we print. For A, we have:

```
             ?>}<?light
_               ?_>.>.>.>.>.
```

which executes `>}<` to position us on the last `?` in Chuck's tape, and then runs `>.` five times to print "light".

On the other hand, for part B, we have:

```
                          ?>}>>?dark?
_                _>.>.>.>.>.
```

which executes `>}>>` to position us on the first `.` in Chuck's tape, and then runs `>.` *four* times to print "dark".

Answer (score 4):

### Brainfuck, 132 bytes

```
>,>,[<->-]<[->+<[->-]<[<]>]<++++++++++[->++++++++++<]>>[<++++++++.---.--.+.++++++++++++.>->+<]>-[<<.---.+++++++++++++++++.-------.<]
```

I tried coming up with my own mod 2 algorithm, which is the `[->+<[->-]<[<]>]`.

Answer (score 4):

## Batch, <s>248</s> <s>223</s> 207 bytes

Because Batch lacks disjunctional conditionals. -18 bytes thanks to @dohaqatar7, and more due to his idea.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET S=SET 
%S%/P I=
%S%L=%I:~0,1%
%S%I=IF %L%==
%S%N=%I:~-1%
%S%A= %S%L=
%I%a%A%0
%I%b%A%1
%I%c%A%0
%I%d%A%1
%I%e%A%0
%I%f%A%1
%I%g%A%0
%I%h%A%1
%S%/A R=N%%2
IF %R%%L% (ECHO light) ELSE (ECHO dark)
```

Comment: I'm not on a windows machine so I can't test right now but, you should be able to save some bytes by abusing variable expansion. Put `set a=" set L="` at the top then replace every occurrence of ` set L=` with `%a%`.

Comment: @dohaqatar7 Oh right you can do that. Thanks!

Comment: when `SET` is used with switches (`/A` or `P`) spaces are ignored, like `%S%/P I=` can be shortened into `%S%/PI=`. Furthermore, parenthesis around `ECHO dark` isn't required

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, <s>147</s> <s>127</s> 126 bytes

```
@set/pi=
@set/aj=%i:~1%%%2
@goto %i:~,1%
:a
:c
:e
:g
@set/aj=1-j
:b
:d
:f
:h
@if %j%==0 (echo dark)else echo light
```

Uses `goto` as a form of `switch` to increment the row number on alternate columns.

Edit: Saved 15 bytes by reducing the column modulo two up front and then using `1-j` to flip between dark and light on alternate columns. Saved 2 bytes by removing some unnecessary `()`s. Saved <s>3</s> 4 bytes by removing some unnecessary spaces.

Answer (score 4):

### Bash, 40 bytes

```
read x;y=(light dark);echo ${y[19#$x%2]}
```

Not using any coreutils.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + coreutils, <strike>34</strike> 36

Using the same base conversion technique as other answers, but I chose base 19.  I think it should work for any odd base between 19 and 35.

```bash
x=(light dark)
echo ${x[19#`cat`%2]}
```

Comment: Looks like your code reverses the colors. 1 character shorter: `x=(light dark);echo ${x[19#\`cat\`%2]}`

Comment: @manatwork Thanks.  When I tried the array indexing trick before it turned out longer - not sure what I got wrong.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### CMD.EXE, 15 + 15 + 10 + 63 = 103 bytes

`a1.cmd`:

```
echo dark
exit
```

`a2.cmd`:

```
echo light
exit
```

Then create hard links for all the remaining 62 squares. Invoke using `cmd /k echo off`.

Comment: It's customary to count each additional file as one byte. That should apply to hard links too.

Comment: I think the consensus is that each additional file after the 1st costs you an extra point.  I would argue that hard links count as files for this purpose.

Comment: @Dennis you beat me to it by 35 seconds.  Business as usual ;-)

Answer (score 3):

### [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/wiki), 22 bytes

```
ii+2%Q"thgil"H|"krad"H
```

#### Explanation

```
ii             Read two chars
+2%            Add code points mod 2
Q        |     If top of stack is truthy...
 "thgil"H        Push "light" and halt, outputting stack
"krad"H        Push "dark" and halt, outputting stack
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>61</s> 56 Bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Mauris

---

As always, Haskell's interact function comes through with some byte saving on a challenge with IO.

The program assumes that a STDIN consists of only the row and the column, anything else can throw off the results; although, a trailing newline will not effect the outcome.

```
main=interact$(cycle["dark","light"]!!).sum.map fromEnum
```

Comment: `main=interact$(cycle["dark","light"]!!).sum.map fromEnum` for 56 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, <s>29</s> 27 bytes

```
$_=/./&($'+ord)?light:dark
```

This code requires the `-p` switch, which I have counted as 1 byte.

Try it online on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/bMUNgW).

#### How it works

- Because of the `-p` switch, Perl reads one line of input and stores it in `$_`.
- `/./` is a regular expression that matches one character. This has two implications:

  - Since the match is successful, `/./` returns **1**.
  - The post-match (second input character) is stored in `$'`.
- `$'+ord` adds the integer the second input character represents to the code point (`ord`) of the first character of the implicit variable `$_`.
- `&` takes the bitwise AND of the return value of `/./` and the sum `$'+ord`, returning **1** is the sum if odd, **0** if it is even.
- `?light:dark` returns **light** if the previous expression returned **1** and **dark** otherwise.
- Finally `$_=` assigns the result to `$_`, which Perl prints automatically, because of the `-p`  switch.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 Bytes

Thanks to @El'endiaStarman for shaving off a byte!

New Method (using fancy stack mechanics):

```
"krad"&"thgil"z+2M(?Z
```

Explanation:

```
"krad"&"thgil"z+2M(?Z
"krad"                 Push "dark" (backwards) to the stack.
      &                Generate a new stack.
       "thgil"         Push "light" (backwards) to the stack.
              z        Grab all input as string.
               +       Add up the input's ASCII values.
                2M     Modulate by 2.
                  (    If the result is not zero, do the next item.
                   ?   Rotate over a stack.
                    Z  Output everything in the current stack.
```

Original Method (using fancy line-specific execution mechanics):

```
z+2M1+mZ
"krad"
"thgil"
```

How it works:

```
z+2M1+mZ
z        Grab all input as string.
 +       Add it together.
  2M     Modulo by 2.
    1+   Add 1
      m  Go to the line specified by the top item of the stack - if it's one,
         it'll push "light" to the stack. If 2, "dark".
       Z Output everything in the stack.
```

Answer (score 3):

**C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) - <s>122</s> 42**

```
Write((Read()+Read())%2<1?"dark":"light");
```

- Reads from STDIN
- Format is simply **a1**

Thanks to [@dana](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8340/dana) for the change from C# to the current one & golfing a ton of bytes! :)

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFVDIyg1MUVDUxtCaaoa2RjaK6UkFmUrWSnlZKZnlChpWv//n2QEAA)

Comment: I got it down to 100, but if you switched to the "Visual C# Interactive" REPL you could do better - https://tio.run/##Sy7WTc4vSv3/v7Q4My9dwdk2uLK4JDVXzzk/rzg/J9U6OSexuFghoLq4JLEkM1mhLD8zRcE3MTNPQ7PaWS@8KLMkVUPDWS8oNTFFQ1MbxtBUNbIxtFdKSSzKVrJSyslMzyhR0rSurf3/P8kIAA

Comment: 42 bytes - https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/vCizJFVDIyg1MUVDUxtCaaoa2RjaK6UkFmUrWSnlZKZnlChpWv//n2QEAA

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>59</s> 56

```
s=prompt()
alert((s.charCodeAt()^s[1])%2?"light":"dark")
```

Extracts the number and the ASCII code of the letter, adds them and checks if even/odd. This can accept input in the form `a1` and `A1`

3 bytes saved thanks to Neil!

Comment: Requires input from STDIN, not a function.

Comment: I didn't see that part. Edited

Comment: You can save a couple of bytes by using `^` instead of `- -` and the `0` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2 - 75 bytes

```
import sys
l,n=sys.stdin.read()
print 'light'if ord(l)&1^int(n)&1 else'dark'
```

Answer (score 3):

## Go, 100 bytes

```
package main;import."os";func main(){t:=Args[1];k,d:=t[0]+t[1],"light";if k%2==0{d="dark"};print(d)}
```

Ungolfed:

```
package main

import . "os" // Import os defines into current namespace

func main() {
    t := Args[1] // Grab the first argument
    // Define k as the sum of the 2 
    // first characters of the first argument, then define d as "light"
    k, d := t[0]+t[1], "light"
    // The sum aligns up nicely with the color of the square        
    if k%2 == 0 {
        d = "dark"
    }
    print(d)
}
```

Comment: You can save a byte using `!k%2` (unless I'm mistaken about precedence)

Comment: @cat Go does not support boolean operators on ints

Comment: Uhh... oh. I forgot about that. Go gets a little lamer every time I come back to it.

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>52</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
("dark","light")[(+($a="$input")[0]+$a[1])%2]
```

Pretty ugly due to how we have to parse the STDIN input (which, in PowerShell, is [weird](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62295/42963)). The special variable `$input` is present only if items get piped in, we encapsulate that into a string, and save it into `$a`. Then, we use the same math trick as other answers to calculate out whether the input is even or odd, and use that to index into our `"dark"` or `"light"` output array.

Edit -- saved 6 bytes by using `+` to cast `$a[0]` instead of `[int]`. Saved an additional byte by changing where `$a` is created by using a code block.

Comment: You can drop 3 bytes by replacing `[int]` with `1*`

Comment: @Rynant Or, use `+` and drop the parens to save 6. ;-)

Comment: Even better; nice!

Answer (score 3):

### Common Lisp, 90 bytes

Not a winner, but makes nice use of ability to read in base 18 and then do arithmetic with that number.

```
(let((*read-base* 18))(if(evenp(multiple-value-call'logxor(floor(read)18)))"light""dark"))
```

Answer (score 3):

### Marbelous, 86 bytes

```
..00
..]]//
&0/\]]//
..&0//
..//
^0
=0&1
&2\/
\/
'l'i'g'h't'd'a'r'k
&1&1&1&1&1&2&2&2&2
```

`]]//` loops wait for two bytes of input, then add them together and use `^0` and `=0` to check the LSB and drop "light" or "dark" to stdout.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 69 Bytes

```
sed 's/^./(&+/;s/$/)%2/'|tr [a-h] [1-8]|bc|sed s/1/light/\;s/0/dark/
```

Probably could be optimized a bit more.

- The first `sed` formats the input to be from the form `a5` to `(a+5)%2`
- `tr` takes the letters a-h and converts them to 1-8 respectively
- `bc` performs the addition and modulo
- the final `sed` then takes the result and formats it as a string.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 20 bytes

```
js2\?'light'}'dark']
```

Explanation

```
j              % input string
s              % sum  
2              % push 2
\              % mod(sum(inputstring),2)
?              % if this value is 1
  'light'      % return 'light'
}              % else  
  'dark'       % return 'dark'
]              % end
```

Comment: Was MATL written before this challenge?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. The first version was published in october as far as I know, but I am not sure whether this is valid code in the first version.

Comment: Yes, the language was in draft in October with a preliminary version of the interpreter also available.  The esolangs.org page was also created at that time... so I think you're good here flawr.

Comment: Vert nice use of `mod`!

Comment: Well I basically just translated my matlab answer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 43 bytes

```julia
print([:dark,:light][sum(read(stdin))%2+1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v6AoM69EI9oqJbEoW8cqJzM9oyQ2urg0V6MoNTFFo7gkJTNPU1PVSNswVvP//yRDAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Shue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242897/golf-the-prime-numbers-in-shue), 80 bytes

```
light
dark
bb=
b=light
=dark
a=
c=
d=b
e=
f=b
g=
h=b
1=
2=b
3=
4=b
5=
6=b
7=
8=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVVNj9owEL37V1ic7ELTZumXIlk97Z4qbQ9VL5BWTjIQq4kd2c5u0ZbfTscOsIFdqm0uZmaen2denkO38bXR851qO2M9tTCjbuOIhZQKjJLStJ1qgNliwtjih8j/LJeCv@JMjKPPE05IBSvaa3Cl7IApnhGKjwWPRMVkEiMsYvQ2/l4ZS0uqNFUDMjxqFSFSV1gSYd9yOXks7wmn@8JJfkwd4@YpmbjAJf6fSl9qS7@M62y3VA7od9n0cG2tsWw1@SqtA0shhBldG0/LWlpZekw@lFsqV@EXqsBPuS/pNjSSjsAOnh1h48GxRZkPvOfdvqjT69svb65vb857xAN6q8NCBrd0YefRKohtlZbeWIedOvBsv61v4DTTKB0zKnFdozyLsvOjq5rgqoh57LuNdk6TVvqyZg0fW65N1tb0HZvzM0HCwX8EfWBHWx@gKecz@iQ754s0yznf/kPl0ZSB@jnm7VitEX42dDRoB7@h7D2wckbHAh5AOO6gbjmM2mt1Bxhj/kENB7Smwuib7SGG9zXe85AciRYRNxKHOOY03P8ckT2@lIP6Lqh/QJzOjlrHamw02w/oXro7lOWsCIA44mn1gDCxLvUaWAOaOT5N@VPkoZuFycw04CTPw8WRz0PPBw9vzi0yk0@LKXLsGbJ8e3H3mdhnr2TMTS5dM2vWVraHe6YNOqRrZAktaO@otEA745wq8C2iYdEjeAMqWkAt75TpLQ/faFKaCg/E7/Fk16h17Ukl7S9SFIIUYkiImJGClIJUoiAgyAqXtSA1LqkgV7jMBXmHy3tBPuDyUZBPotghKfr/dZoTonQXzLFxifOV0okFWTGegA7no2HwDyZY9GhizKKPdcdJZ5X2DMtJBQOY74qrvw)

Pretty sure this is optimal. The empty string represents even letters/integers and a "b" represents odd letters/integers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
readln Σ odd? "light""dark"? print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcaxDYAgEAXQVX4YwNJCC0tjY2McgHCnEPHQEydyH1fCxFe9xbqctMzTMPYNQsLF583i@MJus8fGKhz/V7cEl4jRFmVLUfA@SEQdTAyrz8aQ1c10ODRILmWtPw)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 25 bytes

```
{$[2!+/x;"light";"dark"]}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pWiTZS1NavsFbKyUzPKFGyVkpJLMpWiq3l4kqLVkoyVIpV0FcAS4H46Wao/BQTMB+kBcRNNEThZqDpTjSGSwMAL5oiMw==)

Simple if statement.

Explanation:

```
{$[2!+/x;"light";"dark"]}    Main function. Takes x as input
 $[                    ]     If
     +/x                     Sum of ASCII charcodes of x
    !                        Modulo by
   2                         2
        ;                    If the result is 1 (i.e. an odd number)
         "light"             Return string "light"
                ;"dark"      Else, return string "dark"
```

Comment: hint: use indexing, symbols, and a train shorten it by ≈⅓

Answer (score 2):

## Microscript, 25 bytes

Because Microscript II really doesn't have much in terms of character manipulation yet.

```
2sI++%{"thgil"ah}"krad"ah
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 40 <s>42</s> bytes

PHP is doing OK this time:

```
<?=intval(fgets(STDIN),35)%2?dark:light;
```

---

**Edits**

- *Saved* **2 bytes** by using `<?=` instead of `echo`. Thanks to [Martijn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21443/martijn).

Comment: 40 chars: `<?=intval(fgets(STDIN),35)%2?dark:light;`

Comment: @Martijn Sometimes you can't see the simplest things. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

## [ShapeScript](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```
0'1+@"%c"2?862**+%$"%d"2?%~@'8*!#!+"dark"@"light"@'@'*!#
```

[Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=MCcxK0AiJWMiMj84NjIqKislJCIlZCIyPyV-QCc4KiEjISsiZGFyayJAImxpZ2h0IkAnQCcqISM=&input=YjE=)

#### How it works

```
0         Push 0 (accumulator).
'         Push a string that, when evaluated, does the following:
  1+        Increment the accumulator.
  @         Swap it with the input.
  "%c"      Push that formatting string.
  2?        Copy the accumulator.
  862**+    Add 8 * 6 * 2 = 96 to it.
  %         Apply the string formatting: 1 ... 8 -> 'a' ... 'h'
  $         Split the input at occurrences of that character.
  "%d"      Push that formatting string.
  2?        Copy the accumulator.
  %         Apply the string formatting: 1 ... 8 -> '1' ... '8'
  ~         Join the split input, using that character as separator.
  @         Swap the result with the accumulator.
'
8*        Repeat the string eight times.
!         Evaluate.
#         Discard the accumulator.
!         Evaluate the modified input. Pushes two integers.
+         Add the integers.
"dark"@   Swap the sum with that string.
"light"@  Ditto.
'@'*!     Repeat the at sign (swap) that many times and evaluate the result.
          An odd number of swaps brings "dark" on the top of the stack.
#         Discard the topmost string.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Mouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_(programming_language)), 25 bytes

```
?'?'+2\["light"$]"dark"$
```

Explanation:

```
?'?'                       ~ Read two characters from STDIN and put their ASCII
                           ~ codes on the stack
    +2\                    ~ Get the sum of the codes modulo 2
       ["light"$]          ~ If the result is 1, print light to STDOUT and exit
                 "dark"$   ~ Print dark to STDOUT and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS - 59 bytes

My original version (before looking at any other answers) was 117 bytes and probably reflects the way I come at a problem. Then I saw everyone using base 19 or 35, which wouldn't have sprung to my mind at all.

So, with thanks to everyone else for getting this down to 59.

```
1 INPUT s$: PRINT IIF$(DECIMAL(s$,19) MOD 2,"Dark","Light")
```

Prints "Dark" if converted number mod 2 is 1/True and "Light" otherwise, using the inline if statement.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 163 bytes

Thanks to Alex A. for helping me with this answer.

```
n<-toupper(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),"")));cat(matrix(rep(c(rep(c("light","dark"),4),rep(c("dark","light"),4)),4),8,8,dimname=(list(8:1,LETTERS[1:8])))[n[2],n[1]])
```

#### Example usage

```
1: b1
2: 
Read 1 item
light

1: d4
2: 
Read 1 item
dark
```

There's surely a better way to do this. I just made a matrix filled with the string "light" or "dark" to match the chessboard and then used subscripts taken from the input to return the color of the square.

Comment: Alright, I took your suggestions and fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's some [tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4024) for golfing in R.  Couple of things that stand out.  Replace `<-` with `=`.  `toupper` isn't required, but you'll need to use `letters` rather than `LETTERS`.   You could create a 9 x 9 matrix using `matrix(c('dark','light'),9,9)`.  It will throw a warning, but I don't think that's a problem.  You could also play around with `charToRaw`.  So keeping the same sort of logic you could reduce it to something like `cat(matrix(c('dark','light'),9,9)[(n=as.integer(charToRaw(scan(,'')))-c(96,48))[1],n[2]])`

Answer (score 2):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 31 bytes

```
ii+2%?\"krad"oooo;
l"oc0.\"thgi
```

Here I'm thinking "there's got to be a better way..."

Answer (score 2):

## R, 65 bytes

```r
cat(c("dark","light")[1+sum(strtoi(charToRaw(scan(,"")),16))%%2])
```

Ungolfed:

```r
# Get the ASCII codes from the input string
a <- strtoi(charToRaw(scan(, "")), 16L)

# Compute the sum modulo 2
s <- sum(a) %% 2

# Use the sum as an index for the output
cat(c("dark", "light")[s + 1])
```

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCNZQz0lsShbXUc9JzM9o0RdM9pQu7g0V6O0JM0iJN8zr0SjODkxT0NHXV1TU1NV1ShW83@S4X8A "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

**Scala, <s>65</s> <s>53</s> 49 bytes**

It's quite clear without ungolfing.

```
print(Seq("dark","light")(readLine.sum.toInt%2))
```

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 21 bytes

```
{^}*~1&"lightdark"5/=
```

Explanation:

```
{^}*            # XOR the bytes of the input together
~               # negate the result
1&              # extract only the lowest bit (i.e. 0 or 1)
"lightdark"5/   # split the string "lightdark" into the array ["light" "dark"]
=               # use the bit as an index into the array, returning "light"
                # for 0 and "dark" for 1
```

Conveniently, since the ASCII codes of a Unix-style newline (LF = ASCII 10) and a space (ASCII 32) are even, this code can handle arbitrary spaces and linefeeds in its input.  Both upper- and lowercase letters are also accepted, and the letter can be given before or after the number.  Tabs or carriage returns, however, will throw it off.

Not unexpectedly, this program is quite similar to [Peter Taylor's CJam entry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63773).  I didn't actually look at any of the other entries before I wrote this, though.

Answer (score 2):

### Burlesque, 25 bytes

```
)**++"dark light"wdcyj!!Q
```

One-to-one translation from the 56 bytes Haskell solution to this challenge:

```
)**++             -- sum . map fromEnum
"dark light"wdcy  -- cycle["dark","light"]
j                 -- swap
!!                -- same as Haskell !!
```

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog, 80 bytes

```
p:-read(X),string_codes(X,[A,B]),Y is(A+B)mod 2,(Y=0->write(dark);write(light)).
```

Try it online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/)

Comment: `/\1` instead of `mod 2` + removing the parens around `(A+B)` saves a few bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [PlatyPar](https://github.com/cyoce/PlatyPar), 21 bytes

```
X,u#^2%?"dark"\"light
```

Explanation

```
X,u#^                  ## charcode of the letter XOR the number
     2%?      \        ## if it is odd
        "dark"         ## output "dark"
               "light  ## else output "light
```

[Try it online](https://rawgit.com/cyoce/PlatyPar/master/page.html?code=X%2Cu%23%5E2%25%3F%22dark%22%5C%22light)!

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 53 Bytes

```
l,n=(...):byte(1,2)print(l%2==n%2 and"dark"or"light")
```

Pretty simple, takes command line input through `...` and assigns variables `l` and `n` to the first and second byte of the input and then checks the ASCII value of each. If both are even or both are odd, the square is dark, else the square is light.

Answer (score 2):

## ><> Fish 26 bytes

```
d"darkthgil"ii+2%?!rooooo;
```

A spin on the already posted fish code by [sp3000](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63912/62009).

It uses the same based checking with mod but with a few changes.

Using 1 line allows us to save 6 bytes (1 for the new line, 2 for directional instructions and 3 for the jump instructions)

Lose 1 byte to placing a [CR] onto the stack but it allows us to use 5 prints on both answers.

Lose 1 byte to reversing the stack [r] when needed for an answer.

Lastly putting both answers on the stack in 1 string allows us to save 2 bytes not having to use ["] twice.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 66 bytes

```
INPUT L$N=INSTR(@bdfh,L$)<0!=VAL(POP(L$))MOD 2?"light"*N;"dark"*!N
```

explanation:

```
INSTR(@bdfh,L$)<0 'Checks if L$ is b,d,f,h. @bdfh is a label, equivalent to the string "@bdfh"
!= 'used as a logical XOR, which SB doesn't have.
VAL(POP(L$))MOD 2 'Checks if the row is odd. Also removes the second character of L$, 
                   'which makes the first check shorter since SB evaluates right to left.
?"light"*N;"dark"*!N 'this turned out to be shorter than using IF/THEN/ELSE.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 16 bytes

```
`dark`light 2!+/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P80qISWxKDshJzM9o0TBSFFb/3@auoZSkqGStVK6GZBIMVHS/A8A)

`+/` sum the (code points of the) argument

`2!` mod-2

`` `dark`light ``  select that from this list of symbols

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
OḂEị“_ß“ṗɠ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4Y4m14e7ux81zIk/PB9IPtw5/eSCQ7v/P9y95eiew@2PmtaoZAEJoIyCrp3Co4a5kf//JxlypZtxpZgAAA)

Comment: Why not just `OSị“ṗɠ“_ß»` for 10 bytes?

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
C∑₂`⟇ǎ↔β`½i
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJD4oiR4oKCYOKfh8eO4oaUzrJgwr1pIiwiIiwiYTciXQ==)

Explanation:

```
C∑₂`⟇ǎ↔β`½i ; takes the coordinate
C           ; character values of the input
 ∑          ; sum of char values
  ₂         ; is even?
   `⟇ǎ↔β`   ; compressed string "lightdark"
         ½  ; split in half (yielding ["light", "dark"])
          i ; index into
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$11\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 9.054 bytes

```
iHD,[jn("OS
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJpSEQsW2puKFwiT1MiLCJhNyJd)

```
iHD,[jn("OS
          S # Sum charcodes
         O  # Is odd?
i           # Use that as the index for...
  D,[jn("   # The compressed string "darklight"
 H          # Halved, yielding ["dark", "light"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 31 bytes

```haskell
main=io$(Wr"dark light"!)<mF Or
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYv9uYmZebaZ-Soa4UVKKYlF2Qo5mekZJUqKmja5bgr-RRBVC6DUohQTCAsA)

### Explanation

All in all we sum the code points and select the correct color based on its value mod 2.

- `Or` converts a character to its codepoint
- `mF Or` folds along a string to sum up the codepoints
- `Wr` splits the string `"dark light"` along spaces.
- `!` indexes the string wrapping around if the index is greater than 1.
- `io` converts a function into a complete program
- `main=` sets the main and is required by Haskell for complete programs

### Reflection

hgl is not good for complete programs. It has the 5 byte penalty forced by a main declaration, and requires some type glue, in this case `io`, to work. 8 bytes here are devoted to making this a complete program.

This challenge also has stringent `io` which contributes a lot to the size of the program.

With that in mind the actual logic here is 5-6 bytes which is alright.

Some reflections:

- hgl has no string compression. Obviously, since it can't have dedicated syntax, it wouldn't be as effective as other golfing languages, and it would also be a large undertaking to implement it.  But it potentially could have saved in this challenge.
- There's an argument to be had that `Wr` should be 1 byte. If you want to make lists of strings, `Wr"..."` is usually the way to go.
- `(!)` does not seem to have a prefix variant. It wouldn't help here, even if it were 1 byte, but it should probably exist with a 2-byte name.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
=+.@o$%`D-21~8fd905cff4e
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWO2y19RzyVVQTXHSNDOss0lIsDUyT09JMUiHSUFULViQZcqWbcaWYQPgA)

#### Explanation

```
   @                      - input
  . o$                    - as codepoints
 +                        - sum
=     %`D-21~8fd905cff4e  - index in compressed list ["light", "dark"] (wrapped)
```

-2 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen

Comment: Nice!  You can also save one byte (2 nibbles) using data to encode the "light" "dark" array: ```=%+.@o$2%`D-21~8fd905cff4e```...

Comment: Also, Nibbles indexing wraps around by default, so you can leave-out the ```%2``` altogether to save another byte: ```=+.@o$%`D-21~8fd905cff4e```

Answer (score 1):

## AHK, 78 bytes

```
a=%1%
If Mod(Asc(a)+Asc(SubStr(a,2)),2)=1
s=light
Else
s=dark
FileAppend,%s%,*
```

AHK uses `1` as the name for the first parameter so you have to assign to a different name before you use it in functions. Otherwise, it'll think you mean the value 1 and not the variable *named* `1`. Also, the only way to report to `STDOUT` is by using `FileAppend` with `*` as the file name.

Answer (score 1):

## [Chip](https://github.com/Phlarx/chip), 57 bytes

```
*gS!~s
fA.Z\ZZZvt
cZ}x< eab
>--^/vZZvZZvt
ZZZd ddac ce
ab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87ILPj/Xys9WLGumCvNUS8qJioqqqyEKzmqtsJGITUxictOVzdOvwwoCBYHyqYopKQkJiskp3IlJv3/n24GAA)

XOR's the low bit of each input (like most if not all other answers) to make the decision. Outputs `` dabh` ``, bitwise-OR'd with `` hhe`t `` for light or ``` ``pc ``` for dark. (Dark also exits one byte early).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 16 bytes

```
`ä•Krk`qe g~Uxc
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=YOSVBEtya2BxZSBnflV4Yw==&input=LW0gWwpbJ2EnLCcxJ10sClsnYicsJzEnXSwKWydnJywnNiddLApbJ2QnLCc0J10KXQ==)

#### How it works

```
`ä•Krk`qe g~Uxc

`ä•Krk`          Compressed literal for "lightedark"
        qe        Split with "e"
           g      Take the element at the index (wrapping)...
             U      Input array of chars
              xc    Sum the chars' charcodes
            ~       Take bitwise not, in order to swap parity
```

[The string array compression trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/142629/78410) did quite a job here.

Comment: [15 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=YLtyayCmZ2h0YLhnVXhj&input=WwpbImEiIjEiXQpbImIiIjEiXQpbImciIjYiXQpbImQiIjQiXQpdLW1S)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 13 bytes

```
“–°‡Ž“#I35öÈè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcOcRw2TD2141LDw6F4gR9nT2PTwtsMdh1f8/59kCAA)

Here is a golf with your own language :)

### Explanation

```
“–°‡Ž“       : compressed: "dark light"
      #      : split by space
            è: select the 0th or 1st element based on {
       I35ö  :  take the input and convert it to int from base 35
           È :  1 if even else 0
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>25</s> 24 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-1 thanks to Bubbler.

```apl
⊃'dark' 'light'⌽⍨+/⎕UCS⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jrmb1lMSibHUF9ZzM9IwS9Uc9ex/1rtDWf9Q3NdQ5@FHvPJC6/wpgUMCVZMgFY6abwZkpJgA)

`⍞` get text from stdin

`⎕UCS` convert to Universal Character Set code points

`+/` sum

`'dark' 'light'⌽⍨` use that to cyclically rotate the list of strings

`⊃` pick the first

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkGXI862gv@P@pqVk9JLMpWV1DPyUzPKFF/1LP3Ue8KbX2gulDn4Ee98/4D1f1XAIMCriRDLhgz3QzOTDEBAA).

Comment: @Bubbler [23](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FXs3pKYlG2uoJ6TmZ6Ron6o569j3pXGD7qWvqob2qoc/D/tEdtEx719gEVPupd86h3y6H1xo/aJgIlg4OcgWSIhydQjXqSoTpXmnq6GYhMMVEHAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online").

Comment: OP requires a full program, so the 23 is invalid.

Comment: @Bubbler Oh. Hm.

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 25 bytes

```
iu+2%1(8*?"light"@"dark"@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z@zVNtI1VDDQsteKSczPaNEyUEpJbEoW8nh//9kYwA)

How it works

```
>                      implicit entry
 i                     read string from input
  u                    break the string into characters
   +                   add them together
    2%                 modulo 2
      1(               compare with 1
        8*             multiply the result (true -> 8, false -> 0)
          ?            pop x, if x is truthy, skip x characters
           "light"@    output light if false
           "dark"@     ouput dark if true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 12 bytes

```
+2%[‘15‘|‘1⑻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f20g1@lHDDENTIFEDYjyauPv//3Sz/7qZRQA)

A Keg port of Dennis' answer.

Comment: This is the obvious approach to a trivial question, so I wouldn't consider this a port (or am I missing something?)

Comment: I saw Dennis' answer and copied it. It uses the same algorithm as his answer, as in the explanation would pretty much be the same.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes

```python
print('ldiagrhkt'[int(input(),35)%2::2])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

Port of Dennis's GS2 answer.

```
“–°‡Ž“#IÇOè
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOcRw2TD2141LDw6F4gR9nzcLv/4RX//6eYAAA)

### Explanation

```
“–°‡Ž“      Compressed string "dark light"
      #     Split on spaces
       I    Take an input
        Ç   Codepoints
         O  Sum
          è Modular index into the original list
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÄºÉ╨φr°mißâ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8ea790d0ed72f86d69e183&i=%22d4%22)

### Explanation

```
|+            Sum the codepoints of the input string
  `ASbEx!"`   Compressed string "dark light"
           j  Split on spaces. ["dark","light"]
            @ Fetch at the corresponding index (modular)
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>36</del> 35 bytes

```
00000000: b408 cd21 8ad0 cd21 32c2 ba1e 01d0 e873  ...!...!2......s
00000010: 02b2 18b4 09cd 21c3 6c69 6768 7424 6461  ......!.light$da
00000020: 726b 24                                  rk$
```

Listing:

```
B4 08       MOV  AH, 8              ; DOS read char from STDIN 
CD 21       INT  21H                ; first char in AL 
8A D0       MOV  DL, AL             ; move to DL  
CD 21       INT  21H                ; second char in AL 
32 C2       XOR  AL, DL             ; XOR ASCII values to get low bit 
BA 011F     MOV  DX, OFFSET D       ; default to "dark" string 
D0 E8       SHR  AL, 1              ; put low bit into CF 
73 03       JNC  TO_STDOUT          ; if 1, output "dark" 
B2 18       MOV  DL, LOW OFFSET L   ; otherwise, "light" 
        TO_STDOUT: 
B4 09       MOV  AH, 9              ; DOS write string to STDOUT 
CD 21       INT  21H                ; DX written to STDOUT 
C3          RET                     ; return to DOS 
                 
        L   DB   'light$' 
        D   DB   'dark$'
```

Just does a simple `XOR` on the ASCII values of the two chars and the lowest order bit determines which string to output.

Standalone executable DOS program (since STDIN/STDOUT is a requirement).

[image]

-1 byte thx to @l4m2!

Comment: `BA 0119     MOV  DX, OFFSET L  ` => `MOV DL, L` as they're in same 256B

Answer (score 1):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 138 bytes

```
N+N
Count i while _%2 {
Write 108
Write 105
Write 103
Write 104
Write 116
0
}
Count i while _ {
Write 100
Write 97
Write 114
Write 107
0
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xOTkr6/99P24/LOb80r0QhU6E8IzMnVSFe1Uihmiu8KLMkVcHQwALOMoWzjOEsExjL0IzLgKsW3SQkcwygLEtzuBa4ZgNzkOb//5OMAA)

#### Pseudocode

```
Read two characters, add their codepoints, and store the result in the accumulator
While the accumulator value is odd:
    Write l, i, g, h, t
    Set the accumulator to 0
While the accumulator value is nonzero:
    Write d, a, r, k
    Set the accumulator to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 32 bytes

```
dark&light&\|!I<gI0nr`gI1R1+\%b`
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=dark%26light%26%5C%7C!I%3CgI0nr%60gI1R1%2B%5C%25b%60&inputs=d2)

## Explanation

This essentially just takes the sum of the number and the ASCII value of the letter, sees if it's even or odd, and outputs "dark" or "light" accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `B`, \$17 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 14 bytes

```
S"ldiagrhkt"ZlsAH
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYbg5VyUjIT04syskuUonKKHT0g4lDppdFKTkqxi5IMIVwA)

```python
S"ldiagrhkt"ZlsAH   # Implicit input. The B flag gets the ordinals of each character in the input.
S                   # Sum the ordinals
 "ldiagrhkt"        # String "ldiagrhkt"
            Zl      # Uninterleaved to get ['light', 'dark']
              sAH   # Index into this list (1-based, modular)
                    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 97 bytes

```go
package main
import."os"
func main(){o:="light"
if(Args[1][0]+Args[1][1])%2<1{o="dark"}
print(o)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BgqWlJWm6FjcTCxKTsxPTUxVyEzPzuDJzC_KLSvSU8ouVuNJK85LBohqa1flWtko5mekZJUpcmWkajkXpxdGGsdEGsdowpmGspqqRjWF1vq1SSmJRtlItV0FRZl6JRr5mLcQiqH3LopWSDJVioTwA)

-3 byte improvement over [@Kristoffer Sall-Storgaard's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64047/77309).

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -Rr, 31 bytes

```
["dark","light"][explode|add%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z9aKSWxKFtJRyknMz2jRCk2OrWiICc/JbUmMSVF1Sj2//8kQ650M64Uk3/5BSWZ@XnF/3WDigA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), 42 bytes

```
say «dark light»[slurp.comb».ord.sum%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gh3ploio7y)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `B`, 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
S‘ɲ⁺/^‘½İ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpNS7IKlpSVpuhabgh81zDi56VHjLv04IOvQ3iMblhQnJRdDpRcsSjKEsAA)

##### Explanation

```python
S‘ɲ⁺/^‘½İ  # Implicit input, converted to ordinals by B flag
S          # Sum the list of ordinals of the input
 ‘ɲ⁺/^‘    # Push dictionary compressed string "lightdark"
       ½   # Halve it to get ["light", "dark"]
        İ  # 1-based modularly index the sum into this list
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 178 bytes

```
interface z{static void main(String[]a){int b=a[0].charAt(0)-'a',c=a[0].charAt(1)-'0';if(b%2==0&&c%2!=0||b%2!=0&&c%2==0)System.out.print("dark");else System.out.print("light");}}
```

Takes input as first argument.

Ungolfed:

```
interface z {
    static void main(String[]a) {
        int b = a[0].charAt(0) - 'a',                               // Convert value from a to value from 0...7
                c = a[0].charAt(1) - '0';                           // Get number
        if (b % 2 == 0 && c % 2 != 0 ||                             // If b is divisible by 2 and c is divisible by 2 or
                b % 2 != 0 && c % 2 == 0)                           // b is not divisible and c is divisible
            System.out.print("dark");                               // output dark
        else System.out.print("light");                             // else output light
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 63 bytes

```
scan [gets stdin] %c%d h v
puts [expr ($h+$v)%2?"light":"dark"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/ODkxTyE6PbWkWKG4JCUzL1ZBNVk1RSFDoYyroBQoGJ1aUVCkoKGSoa1SpqlqZK@Uk5meUaJkpZSSWJStFPv/f4bFfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 38 bytes

```
~(asc(;)+!_sA,-1|!)%2|?@Light`\?@Dark
```

### Explanation

```
~(                       IF
  asc( )                 the ascii value of
      ;                  the input string (of the input "b1" only the first char is evaluated by asc())
        + _s ,  |        plus a substring of
            A            A$ (the input, this was assigned to A$ by ;)
              -1         taking only the first char from the right
         !        !      and cast this to num
                   )%2   MODULO 2 (is non-zero, implicit)
|?@Light`                THEN PRINT the literal "Light"
\?@Dark                  ELSE PRINT "Dark" (no terminating ` is needed at EOF)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (Mono)](http://www.mono-project.com/), 63 bytes

```fs
printf(if(stdin.Read()+stdin.Read())%2<1 then"dark"else"light")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWzc3Py///v6AoM68kTSMzTaO4JCUzTy8oNTFFQ1MbmaOpamRjqFCSkZqnlJJYlK2UmlOcqpSTmZ5RoqT5/3@iIQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 45 bytes

```
{if(it.sumBy{it-'@'}%2>0)"light" else "dark"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5NCsIwGET3PcUQkCaLij@7Qqu4ducJok3rR9PEJqkgJWePtc5q4MGb6W3QZNJbajystq4EvwVHphMoavwrqjRTyyls/TRcPjOFIj/ncXOod4Jp6p6BQWmvwBrpehZTOxkMkgwXmDMs@en9iApOyeZKRi3kVILJPVv5a5kJfD3A/ShEFtP9@AU)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>48</s> <s>40</s></sup> 37 bytes

```
>@{&('dark';'light')@{:@#:@+/@(a.&i.)
```

− 8 bytes by replacing `(-2&*@<.@%&2)` with `{:@#:` 
− 3 bytes by removing `@>:`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/7Ryq1TTUUxKLstWt1XMy0zNK1DUdqq0clK0ctPUdNBL11DL1NP9rcqUmZ@QrpCmoZxiqw9lJFur/AQ)

Comment: You can save 8 bytes by taking the sum of the unicode codepoints and taking the result mod 2, instead: `('dark';'light')>@{~2|1#.3&u:` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NdRTEouy1a3VczLTM0rUNe0cquuMagyV9YzVSq3@a3KlJmfkK6QpqGcYqsPZSRbq/wE "J – Try It Online")

Comment: ...and 1 more byte by changing the constant to `;:@'dark light'`

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 29 bytes

```
ir2%+2%[p"light"&o;]p"dark"&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@zyEhV20g1ukApJzM9o0RJLd86tkApJbEoG8j8/z/JEAA)

This just does module math on the column number to pick a light/dark squares.  The even/odd-ness of the row shifts the calculations.

```
ir                            - read 2 digit code in as codepoints, reverse stack
  2%                          - even or odd row?
    +                         - add as offset to column
     2%                       - even or odd?
       [p          ]p         - code block run if odd
         "light"&o;           - print "light" and exit
                     "dark"&o - print "dark"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 109 bytes

Golfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY1BigIxEEX3OUUhCAnM1EIZEcHFLAVdiLgaBilNjNF0OlSXgognmY0IeidvY2O7md1__M9_f_dqRZG6l4cPRS5ZYEsHwkjJ4yiJ847Vu3gNMZQ4EztKSpXLrVsJTCgkOCkA69ZQ1KCJfTWAb2Y6_syEQ_K_ZgDzFASGcLrtZf3ZfxQHijAdvh2YiStXg_5vQXZkxyG5j-6XaXdUrt8kJt2KNpDnzU5a6LncZ2d1x2BBWS-Qco5HPTU17xq_aaR3gLM6qwYuV99r0hM)

```scala
val Q=Integer.parseInt(scala.io.StdIn.readLine,35)%2
println("ldiagrhkt".grouped(2).map(_.apply(Q)).mkString)
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZDPSsNAEMbxmqf4KAiJ1D1YFClE8BjQUxEP4mFMNttpN5uwuy1qyZN4CYI-lE_j5k_F2_z5zTffzMe3y0nTouu-dr48v_45OeOqqa3HhvYkNBklMuOlkjaaGsOA4FqsfJGZKKpfNjL3uCc2OERAIUtUIYnJKrfErbX09rTylo16TpZ4MOyRDiSwJw02za6vDHLCSiru2Mg4-QcU8jUAkw_RkHUyJPEwOcfiMsEpLv54F9iZLpiUXW_9bKg3Yb3XJnbinZtH9uusFxV5rXUwf0BOTiLO5-AEXIJ7QaTpcfcNcrSi2o5n9NbaqI3Gl02f6z7V1Rj9Ag)

```scala
import java.lang.Integer
import scala.io.StdIn

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val input = StdIn.readLine()
    val index = Integer.parseInt(input, 35) % 2
    val s = "ldiagrhkt"
    println(s.zipWithIndex.collect{ case (c, i) if i % 2 == index => c }.mkString)
  }
}
```