# Ungolf batch programs

Tags: code-golf, string, syntax

[This](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/73230/56341) question wants you to golf batch programms. In Batch you can use

```
set x=averylongbatchcommand
%x% arg1
```

which expands to

```
set x=averylongbatchcommand
averylongbatchcommand arg1
```

Your task is it to expand these statements.
As you can also use `set`  for arithmetic purposes like this:

```
set x = 0
set /a x= %x%+1
```

you should ignore the statements where the pattern with `set /a` is applied.
There will never be something like

```
set s=SET
%s% s=%s% a
```

where the variable is assigned using itself as command. But you have to handle things like

```
b:
set a =echo
%a% Hello World!
set a=goto
%a% b
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.

### Testcases

```
set s=set
%s% e=echo
%e% I will have to use this exact thing very often because
%e% it absolutely wouldn't be shorter if i just left out these set statements
```

Expands to:

```
set s=set
set e=echo
echo I will have to use this exact thing very often because
echo it absolutely wouldn't be shorter if i just left out these set statements
```

---

```
set s=set
%s% i=0
set g=goto
:a
if %i%==15 (
%g% e
echo %i%
)
%s% /a i=%i%+1
%g% a
:e
%s% i=0
%g% a
```

Expands to:

```
set s=set
set i=0
set g=goto
:a
if %i%==15(
goto e
echo %i%
)
set /a i=%i%+1
goto a
e:
set i=0
goto a
```

---

```
set s=set
%s% s=%s% a=
```

Mustn't be supported.

---

```
set a=echo
%a% Hi
set a=type
%a% log.txt
```

Expands to:

```
set a=echo
echo Hi
set a=type
type log.txt
```

---

```
set x = 0 
set /a x= %x%+1
```

Expands to:

```
set x = 0
set /a x= %x%+1
```

Comment: I meant you shouldn't expand statements with /a.

Comment: Whats is the valid character set for variable names ? Can variable names have more than 1 character ? What if there is more than one `=` on a `set` line ? What is the behaviour of whitespace before or after `=` ?  In particular does space after `=` become part of the assigned value ? Can the whitespace be tabs ? What is the behaviour of lines with an odd number of `%` ?

Comment: For this question you can assume that every variable name is 1 character from a-z case-insensitive. Also whitespaces before the first `=` are ignored. But everything *after* the first `=` including other `=` will be put in the variable.

Comment: Why doesn't `i` get set to `0` in the second testcase ?

Comment: @TonHospel I was confused by this as well, but the line before and after that example are meant to be read as one sentence, saying that references inside lines that start with `set /a` should not be substituted.

Comment: @MartinEnder Even so `if %i%==15` should get substituted. Or does ignoring `/a` work backward ? And I'd like the op to clarify if it's OK to expand variables in `set /a` lines as long as no actual set is executed

Comment: @TonHospel `%i%` doesn't get replaced because it would require iterating the substutition (in the original input the line that will ultimately set `i` doesn't contain `set` yet).

Comment: @MartinEnder I Still don't understand. In the first testcase that is exactly how `e` gets set

Comment: @TonHospel Oh, I did not see that. In that case, I agree that the spec is still not clear. Putting on hold until this is resolved.