# Number Spiral Problem

Tags: code-golf, math

A number spiral is an infinite grid whose upper-left square has number 1. Here are the first five layers of the spiral:

[image]

**Your task is to find out the number in row y and column x.**

---

Example:

```
Input: 2 3
Out  : 8
Input: 1 1
Out  : 1
Input: 4 2
Out  : 15
```

---

Note:

1. Any programming language is allowed.
2. This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge so shortest code wins.
3. Best of Luck!

Source: https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1071

Comment: @WW What does that mean ?

Comment: It looks like your inputs are 1 indexed (coordinates start at 1,1) (although this has to be intuited from the test cases) can we use 0 indexing (coordinates start at 0,0)?

Comment: @WW No. The coordinates should start at 1,1. Sorry.

Comment: What is the reasoning for this?

Comment: @WW No reason. Just arbitrary

Comment: I think it's absolutely fine for the coordinates to start at (1, 1), especially if the program is posted that way on CSES, and the OP doesn't need to justify this. I think golfers here are getting a little too used to somewhat arbitrary freedoms.

Comment: @Lynn I second that

Comment: [For circular spiral see this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/125966/wind-me-a-number-snake).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

(Originally) Adapted from [Doorknob's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170795/58974) over a few beers.

```
wV
nU²ÒNra
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=d1YKblWy0k5yYQ&input=OAo4)

```
wV\nnU²ÒNra     :Implicit input of integers N=[U=y, V=X]
wV              :Maximum of U & V
  \n            :Reassign to U, leaving the value in N unchanged
    n           :Subtract U from
     U²         :  U squared
       Ò        :  Subtract the bitwise NOT of
        Nr      :  N reduced by
          a     :    Absolute difference
```

Answer (score 20):

### C (gcc),  <s>44</s>  43 bytes

```c
f(x,y,z){z=x>y?x:y;z=z*z-~(z%2?y-x:x-y)-z;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7BDoIwDAbgu0/RkJBssh0AvTAnL@LFQGY4iAQxWUfw1ecmQlzoZfu7L@0qfqsqaxXRDJmho5H6jKUuUBhp9oa/iYmzErkuNEfKjZjs/dq0hMK4A1fq0QNp2gE0SEiFO04SjgKSRC8kYDgzXBn@M19d75wiUZzXEQP/MUBKxWqm9da9hieJot/b3A97yyxFMpZTtzquL@13qs8blLI0QD5v0IFlAfLZocl@AA)

The spiral has several "arms":

```
12345
22345
33345
44445
55555
```

The position \$(x, y)\$ is located on arm \$\max(x, y)\$ (assigned to variable `z`). Then, the largest number on arm \$n\$ is \$n^2\$, which alternates between being in the bottom left and top right position on the arm. Subtracting \$x\$ from \$y\$ gives the sequence \$-n+1, -n+2, \ldots, -1, 0, 1, \ldots, n-1, n-2\$ moving along arm \$n\$, so we choose the appropriate sign based on the parity of \$n\$, adjust by \$n-1\$ to get a sequence starting at 0, and subtract this value from \$n^2\$.

Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for saving a byte.

Comment: `f(x,y,z){z=x>y?x:y;z=z*z-~(z%2?x-y:y-x)-z;}` saves 1 byte.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Neat trick, thanks!

Comment: [Crossed out 44 is still regular 44 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/very-simple-triangles/48101#comment113015_48101)

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Why?

Comment: Correct me if I'm missing something. The input should be an x and y coordinate and the output is the number in row y and column x. This looks like the output is the spiral itself.

Comment: @RobertS. You are right!

Comment: @Doorknob You must output the number in row y and column x, not the spiral itself.

Comment: @JonathanFrech What do you mean ?

Comment: @RobertS. Yes, that is what the function I defined does (in the *Code* section on TIO). For instance, `f(1, 1)` returns the value `1`. The *Footer* section loops through x=1 through 5 and y=1 through 5, calls the function for all such values, and prints its output in a grid, to demonstrate that the function is correct for all inputs shown in the question.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle The function does return the number (it couldn't output the spiral - it doesn't even have any loops!).

Comment: @Doorknob I got it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

### Python,  <s>54</s>   <s>50</s>  49 bytes

```
def f(a,b):M=max(a,b);return(a-b)*(-1)**M+M*M-M+1
```

-4 bytes thanks to @ChasBrown

-1 bytes thanks to @Shaggy

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBCoMwFETX9RTZ5Sd@hcRCwWJvkBOIYKSmVWiUNIKePtUUCt0Mj2HezJt/TlaGcO8NMaCxY6WqXnqNeHW9X5wFnXWMQyYY5ypVXGUqFcFMjqy4kcGSupZYNFgLFHueUe4p8dw0ZXKa3WA9gX3JkFY3iiZyEvsknhwXTttHDwIv7OdQmo/TYKH9Gm3uxuXtoWDksLZ/i4UP)

First time golfing! I'm more than aware this is not optimal, but whatever.

Essentially runs on the same principle as @Doorknob C code.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! In this case you can save 4 bytes using the `def f(a,b):` approach, see [here](https://tio.run/##VYxBCoMwFETX9RTZ5Sd@hcRCwWJvkBOIYKSmVWiUNIKePtUUCt0Mj2HezJt/TlaGcO8NMaCxY6WqXnqNeHW9X5wFnXWMQyYY5ypVnMtMpSKYyZEVNzJYUtcSiwZrgWLPM8o9JZ6bpkxOsxusJ7AvGdLqRtFETmKfxJPjwmn76EHghf0cSvNxGiy0X6PN3bi8PRSMHNb2b7HwAQ).

Comment: @ChasBrown Very interesting, thank you!

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you! I've posted a few challenges, but never been good enough to golf

Comment: In that case, then, welcome to Golf! :) I'm not a Python guy but I'm pretty sure `M**2` can be replaced with `M*M`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you! Will fix right now

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
X>ttq*QwoEqGd*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8KupKRQK7A837XQPUVL@///aBMdBaNYAA)
[Collect and print as a matrix](https://tio.run/##y00syflvaGBVEqWlqOQQ4fk/wq6kpFArsDzftdAzRUv7f2yZoUGq4n8A)

#### How?

*Edit: Same technique as @Doorknob's answer, just arrived at differently.*

The difference between the diagonal elements of the spiral is the arithmetic sequence \$ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, \ldots \$. Sum of \$ n \$ terms of this is \$ n(n - 1) \$ (by the usual AP formula). This sum, incremented by 1, gives the  diagonal element  at position \$ (n, n) \$.

Given \$ (x, y) \$, we find the maximum of these two, which is the "layer" of the spiral that this point belongs to. Then, we find the diagonal value of that layer as \$ v = n(n-1) + 1 \$. For even layers, the value at \$ (x, y) \$ is then \$ v + x - y \$, for odd layers \$ v - x + y \$.

```
X>        % Get the maximum of the input coordinates, say n
ttq*      % Duplicate that and multiply by n-1
Q         % Add 1 to that. This is the diagonal value v at layer n
wo        % Bring the original n on top and check if it's odd (1 or 0)
Eq        % Change 1 or 0 to 1 or -1
Gd        % Push input (x, y) again, get y - x
*         % Multiply by 1 or -1
          % For odd layers, no change. For even layers, y-x becomes x-y
+         % Add that to the diagonal value v
          % Implicit output
```

---

**Alternate 21 byte solution:**

```
Pdt|Gs+ttqq*4/QJb^b*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyClpMa9WLukpLBQy0Q/0CspLklL@///aBMdBaNYAA)
[Collect and print as a matrix](https://tio.run/##y00syflvaGBVEqWlqOQQ4fk/IKWkxrNYu6SksFDLRD/QKykuSUv7f2yZoUGq4n8A)
From the above, we know that the function we want is

$$ f = m * (m - 1) + 1 + (-1)^m * (x - y) $$

where \$ m = max(x, y) \$.

Some basic calculation will show that one expression for max of two numbers is

$$ m = max(x, y) = \frac{x + y + abs(x - y)}{2} $$

Plugging one into another, we [find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%20%3D%20m%20*%20(m%20-%201)%20%2B%201%20%2B%20(-1)%5Em%20*%20(x%20-%20y)%20where%20m%20%3D%20(x%20%2B%20y%20%2B%20abs(x-y))%2F2) that one alternate form for \$ f \$ is:

$$ f = (x-y)\cdot i^{k} + \frac{1}{4}((k-2)\cdot k) + 1 $$

where \$ k = abs(x-y) + x + y  \$.

This is the function the solution implements.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 20 bytes

```
A~Qh.MZQh-+*-GH^_1Q*
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=A%7EQh.MZQh-%2B%2a-GH%5E_1Q%2a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%2C3%0A1%2C1%0A4%2C2&debug=0)

An almost literal translation of [Rushabh Mehta](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82007/rushabh-mehta)['s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/170794/number-spiral-problem/170814#170814).

Explanation:

```
A~Qh.MZQh-+*-GH^_1Q*    | Full code
A~Qh.MZQh-+*-GH^_1Q*QQQ | Code with implicit variables filled
                        | Assign Q as the evaluated input (implicit)
A                       | Assign [G,H] as
 ~Q                     |  Q, then assign Q as
   h.MZQ                |   Q's maximal value.
                        | Print (implicit)
        h-+*-GH^_1Q*QQQ |  (G-H)*(-1)^Q+Q*Q-Q+1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
»Ḃ-*×_‘+»×’$¥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7oc7mnS1Dk@Pf9QwQ/vQ7sPTHzXMVDm09P/h5fqPmta4//8fHW2oo2AYq6MQbaSjYAyiTXQUjGJjAQ)

Uses [Doorknob's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170795/59487). Way too long.

Comment: Alternative: `»Ḃ-*×_‘+»²_»ʋ`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
ṀḂḤ’×I+²_’ṀƲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzoaHO5oe7ljyqGHm4eme2oc2xQNZQNFjm/7//2@iYwQA)

Computes the diagonal term with `²_’Ṁ` and adds/subtracts to the correct index value with `ṀḂḤ’×I`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 76 bytes

```
((({}<>))<>[(({}))]<{({}[()])<>}>)<>{}((){({}[()])({})<><([{}])><>}{}<>{}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDo7rWxk5T08YuGsTU1Iy1qQbS0RqasUCxWjsgUV2roaEJFwQpsrGz0Yiuro3VtAMqAekHm/H/v4mCEQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ZÐ<*>ŠGR}¥+
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna* changing `Èi` to `G`.

Port of [*@sundar*'s MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170815/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6vAEGy27owvcg2oPLdX@/z/aRMcoFgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/m5nl4gr2SwqO2SQpK9v@jDk@w0bI7usA9qPbQUu3/Ov@jjXSMY7miDXUMgaSJjhGYNAGSpjqmYLZpLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Z              # Get the maximum of the (implicit) input-coordinate
               #  i.e. [4,5] → 5
 Ð             # Triplicate this maximum
  <            # Decrease it by 1
               #  i.e. 5 - 1 → 4
   *           # Multiply it
               #  i.e. 5 * 4 → 20
    >          # Increase it by 1
               #  i.e. 20 + 1 → 21
     Š         # Triple swap the top threes values on the stack (a,b,c to c,a,b)
               #  i.e. [4,5], 5, 21 → 21, [4,5], 5
      G }      # Loop n amount of times
       R       #  Reverse the input-coordinate each iteration
               #   i.e. 5 and [4,5] → [5,4]→[4,5]→[5,4]→[4,5] → [5,4]
         ¥     # Calculate the delta of the coordinate
               #  [5,4] → [1]
          +    # And add it to the earlier calculate value (output the result implicitly)
               #  21 + [1] → [22]
```

Comment: `Èi` could be `G`.

Comment: @Emigna Oh smart, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), 90 bytes

```pascal
uses math;var x,y,z:word;begin read(x,y);z:=max(x,y);write(z*z-z+1+(1and z*2-1)*(y-x))end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JchLDoMgEADQq8ySj5hQu5L0MKOMlUSpAVtxLo8m3b28DfOIi5m2sdZvpgwr7rP7YYLSnA33xyd5N9A7REiEXtwrHfevFcvfRwo7CVZsWFstLEYPrB7GSiVOU6Sk6NtaO3he)

Port of [Doorknob's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170795/60517), but [sundar's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170815/60517) gave me idea for `z mod 2*2-1` which I transformed into `1and z*2-1` to remove space.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 34 bytes

```
x = {5, 8};
```

so:

```
m = Max[x];
Subtract @@ x (-1)^m + m^2 - m + 1
```

(*

54

*)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 35 bytes

```julia
x\y=(m=max(x,y))*~-m+1+(-1)^m*(x-y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY2xCoMwFAD3fMXD6cVG6LOdBKfObt2MhaAWUkyUJEKy9NfTFtpuB8dxj33RimLOUaYWTWtUxCgS5@WzMgc6YEX8ZkqMVeJ5c9qGxWJxnX2AUfnZNwVnRm34VQL6Wp4EkCQBZ1kPnLF/dVmtD24fwzyBUcHp@Kk7aKF/3@G@OoigLVBDRwHphwObtN8WlbDjLL8A)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 46 bytes

```
f=(r,c,x)=>r<c?f(c,r,1):r%2-!x?r*r-c+1:--r*r+c
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 39 bytes

```java
x->y->(y-x)*((y=x>y?x:y)%2*2-1)+y*y-y+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZAxa8MwEIX3/IojEJAc2dRup6R26VLoUDqETsGD6thBqSMb6Rx0BP92V7Hd0EGne@@O78Gd5EWGp8PPoM5tYxBOXkcdqjqqOl2ganQUbBdt912rAopaWgsfUmm4LgBm16JE/10adYCzn7EdGqWP@xykOVo@rgK8a3ybic@@/9LS0GdbGomNyaCCdHBhRmHGKHQ8YIxSl9GL2xBfJUESxnxNAYW0joftyFMa97nPwNKihXROAbhCIuARenHXsYD4v34SkNx1P9GqxgAbkSNwM2H5nepH4HzKzd4/5ALoT8T5dt7ZkcXyHDUdRq0/AFZs6dLVwe@O1ZS2q9G3K70U4LwtoIpk29bEHJ@aV@tPw4jzidkvbq8ffgE)

### Credits

- Port of [Doorknob's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170795/16236).

Answer (score 0):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), <s>127</s> <s>118</s> 115 bytes

[Also](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170823/58974) adapted from [Doorknob's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/170795/58974).

```
listen to Y
listen to X
let M be Y is less than X and X-0 or Y-0
let R be M*M-M
let R be-M-Y and Y-X or X-Y
say R+1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in, with each input integer on an individual line)