# Generate this number table

Tags: code-golf, integer, matrix

Given an integer \$1 < n < 10 \$ generate a table like below.

For \$n = 5\$,

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 2 3 4 5
3 3 3 4 5
4 4 4 4 5
5 5 5 5 5
```

For \$n = 8\$,

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8
4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8
5 5 5 5 5 6 7 8
6 6 6 6 6 6 7 8
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
```

Shortest code wins! Trailing whitespace allowed

Output format isn't strict, you can output a 2D list/matrix in any reasonable format.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) and nice first question! For future reference, we recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on challenge ideas before posting them to main. Can the output be a list of lists/matrix, or does it have to be formatted like that? If the formatting is required, what should be the output for \$n = 11\$?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing 1 < n < 10 see edit please

Comment: What are the permitted output formats?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/print-output-the-l-phabet)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, I'm actually _pretty_ sure we've had it with numbers, too, but I can't find it.

Comment: VTCing as unclear as the output format(s) are kinda essential to a challenge like this.

Comment: Please clarify if the output format must be like indicated (and needs some clarification if so) and otherwise specify that outputting in any reasonable format for a matrix of numbers is allowed. In the meantime, I have closed this question until this is clarified.

Comment: And, if the output format _is_ strict, make sure you comment on all existing answers to inform them so.

Comment: Output format isn't strict, you can output a 2D list/matrix too please reopen

Comment: this is [L-phabet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/print-output-the-l-phabet) but with digits instead.

Comment: @BadCoder, what about a 1D-array, [like so](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDvdw&input=OAotUQ)?

Comment: @Shaggy no I think matrices are more suitable for this problem

Answer (score 15):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
»þ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7sP7/h9ud///3wIA)

Outputs an `n x n` matrix. If the output format is required, [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q7sP7Etz///9vAQA)

This is simply a table of maximums. For each cell \$A_{i,j}\$ in the output, the result is equal to \$\max(i,j)\$. The 4 byte answer has `` ` `` to reuse the argument, and `G` to format the output as a grid.

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
∘.⌈⍨⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1HHDL1HPR2Pelc86t38P@1R24RHvX2Pupof9a551Lvl0HrjR20TH/VNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9MUTLnSFCwA)

`∘.⌈⍨` maximum-table for

`⍳` **i**ntegers 1 through the argument

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```
[ [1,b] dup [ max ] cartesian-map ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYs7CgIxEIb7PcV/AHfBQpC1sRMbG7EKKWazowbNw8ks6OljxPZ7XMlpkno5H0@HEYH0PgjFGxc8WCI//yjJzILCr4Wjay4Lq36y@KjYdd0G22pg1qvJYl4yTLvesHAkysVT7ANl2NYMP5pCToUx@X39Ag)

`cartesian-map` Takes two sequences (in this case, both are [1, n]) and applies a quotation to each pair of elements, resulting in a matrix. In effect, we are mapping `max` over a coordinate matrix.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 16 bytes

```
Max~Array~{#,#}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zexos6xqCixsq5aWUe5Vu1/QFFmXkm0Qlq0WaxC7H8A)

Answer (score 6):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v#v), <del>93</del> 89 bytes

```
i,tTv
v`j1<
>I)iIT‹!0jv
 v        <
 >J)jJI≥v_~ v
        >~  v
 ^  v≤TJ<\23<
    `
^   <
```

###### Explanation

`i` pops the top of the stack (by default 0) and stores it into the variable `i`. `,` reads an integer from stdin, then `t` pops it and stores it into variable `t`. `T` pushes to the stack the value of the variable `t` and `v` redirects the intruction pointer towards the end of the next line. `<` tells the instruction pointer to go left. `1` pushes 1 onto the stack and `j` stores it into the variable `j`, and `` ` `` prints a newline. Then `v` and `>` sends the instruction towards the right on the next line. `I` pushes the variable `i`'s value onto the stack, `)` increments it, `i` takes it and puts it into `i`, `I` pushes the value of `i` onto the stack and `T` brings onto the stack the number that was previously read to stdin. `‹` compares them and terminates the program if the grid has finished printing. Then it initializes `j` to 0 and sends the instruction pointer into a loop that increments `j`, then prints a space (`\23` (pointer is currently going left, that's why it is reversed) pushes 32 (ASCII id of " ") and prints it) (`32\` is used instead of `" "~` because it is one character shorter), prints `j` if `j` is lower than `i`, or else prints `i`. When `j` is greater or equal to `t`, it exits the loop, prints a new line and goes back into the outer loop.

In the code, the `t` variable contains the number read from stdin, `i` is the current line number, and `j` is the current character number.

[run online](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#0612ddba136b8e8dbfa17856b3b57444e0a9924d0f4ea1f8756a2793257af9da)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf,](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) and nice first answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
1+>./~@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6zkE6Pm7/DbXt9PTrHDL1/mtypSZn5CukKZjCGBb/AQ)

### Explanation

```
1+>./~@i.    input: n
       i.    range from 0 to n-1 inclusive
    /~       table:
  >.            max(n, n)
1+           add 1 to each
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(n)max([1:n]',1:n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQSNPMzexQiPa0CovVl0HSGr@T8wr1rDQ/A8A)

Comment: For Octave you can actually do this to save 2 bytes: `@(n)max(x=1:n,x')`

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

```r
function(n)outer(1:n,1:n,pmax)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jTzO/tCS1SMPQKk8HhAtyEys0/4elJpfkF2VWpWqkaWoYWVlq/gcA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╗ìΦ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=bb8de8&i=9)

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 40 bytes

```powershell
param($a)1..$a|%{"$(,$_*($_-1)+$_..$a)"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9vyCxKDFXQyVR01BPTyWxRrVaSUVDRyVeS0MlXtdQU1slHiSsqVT7v5aLS00lTcGUS0kJzLD4/x8A)

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x*[x]and[a+[x]for a in f(x-1)]+[[x]*x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBDoMgEEDRtT0FOwExqXVnwkkoizFAO0kdCboYT0/V3cv/@di/K421JvuDZQ4geGLt2AMFB92JtBYBAkkkyf2gfOfOqNnXa@A1CtAnypcZnmp6NLkg7RKNThKV2WK27ZtaEyncUPUP)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ƛ£⁰ƛ¥∴
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%C2%A3%E2%81%B0%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%88%B4&inputs=5&header=&footer=) Returns an array of arrays

```
ƛ      # (1...input) Map...
 £     # Push to register
  ⁰ƛ   # (1...input) Map...
    ¥  # Register
     ∴ # Maximum of the two
```

Or, for grid output, 10 bytes:

```
ƛ£⁰ƛ¥∴;Ṅ;⁋
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C6%9B%C2%A3%E2%81%B0%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%88%B4%3B%E1%B9%84%3B%E2%81%8B&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ       ;  # (1...input) Map...
 £         # Push to register
  ⁰ƛ  ;    # (1...input) Map...
    ¥      # Push register
     ∴     # Max
       Ṅ   # Joined by spaces
         ⁋ # Joined by newlines.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
r=range(1,input()+1)
for x in r:print[x]*x+r[x:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxLCoAgEADQ/ZzCnb82RREFnkRaRFm5GWUwmE5vdYD38lOuhF3d0h6clLKSoxXPoNomYr6L0rbVcCQSLCIKmjNFLJ4Xw5Y8z0v9EAQOm/oLbYbaQQ8DjDC9)

Prints a list for each row.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 19 bytes

```julia
!n=max.((1:n)',1:n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPNjexQk9Dw9AqT1NdB0T@T8ksLshJrNRQNNX8DwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
{x|\x}1+!:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6quqImpqDXUVrTi4kpTMAViCy4AT14FuQ==)

Somewhat surprisingly, using a seeded scan `x|\x` returns the same results as an each-right (`x|/:x`) or each-left (`x|\:x`).

- `1+!:` generate `1..n` from the (implicit) input
- `{x|\x}` set up a scan, seeded with the input, run over the input

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 70 bytes

```cs
a => new int[a][].Select((x,p)=>new int[a].Select((y,q)=>p>q?p+1:q+1))
```

I'm sure there is a shorter way to do this, but I can't find it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEX3/Yqhq4TGQpfaNi5EQXHnwkXtooapBOr0kRTr18co@Lqr4Z7DXGVmymi3GUllmqyA7ZrGKw7VucHs9/ZQSgm1FyEHV0EugfAGvi@qsijjAzaoLGOT6Hguv@gD7qL3oJP9souSRR8lnLs0CFYtmbbB@Dhoi3tNyIwdNF3iXauJhScKxWuVzfn71fQc/7PASxP3Sd0D)

Comment: The first 2 spaces are unnecessary and the first array doesn't need to be multidimentional, saving 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>38</s> 41 bytes

```
Input N
identity(N→[A]
For(I,1,N
For(J,1,N
max(I,J→[A](I,J
End
End
[A]
```

Output is stored as a matrix in `Ans` and is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```rust
|n|(1..=n).fold("".into(),|a,i|(1..=n).fold(a,|b,j|format!("{}{} ",b,i.max(j)))+"
")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3BCsIwEETv@Yp1T7u4BHuWfkyKBra0W6kRCk2@PcbqxbnOzHvr65lqNJiDGjHsDlqme4Ktr9kydd73xj4u040QvVpaiCUH0f8uSB5kzHFZ55BOhHvZC6AMon4OG43MfEaHXK@Hoe1AQQ0ao7v8tJ881qaY7CCgwEbK/L0UV1x9Aw)

The output will be a `String`. The newline is given literally inside quotes, which saves one byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs a 2D-array.

```
õ@õwX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9UD1d1g&input=OAotUQ)

```
õ@õwX     :Implicit input of integer U
õ         :Range [1,U]
 @        :Map each X
  õ       :  Range [1,U]
   wX     :  Max of each with X
```

Or, if outputting a 1D-array is allowed:

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
õ ïw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9SDvdw&input=OAotUQ)

```
õ ïw     :Implicit input of integer U
õ        :Range [1,U]
  ï      :Cartesian product with itself
   w     :Reduce each pair by Max
```

Comment: so close to having `õwõ` but not quite :(

Comment: @hyper-neutrino, wouldn't be a valid Japt programme, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 56 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>x>y++?-~x:y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT0/PsagosVIjTzNWLzexQEMjXqdCJ1HT1i4Rxq0EcirsKrW17XXrKqwqNTX/J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrpGlYAEUA)

Outputs an array of arrays.

Thanks to Shaggy for -5 bytes

Thanks to Arnauld for further -2 bytes

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 71 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>x>y++?-~x:y).join``).join`
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT0/PsagosVIjTzNWLzexQEMjXqdCJ1HT1i4Rxq0EcirsKrW17XXrKqwqNfWy8jPzEhKgNFfC/@T8vOL8nFS9nPx0jTQNC03N/wA)

Outputs string

### History

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>-~x>++y?-~x:y)) // 58

n=>[...m=Array(n)].map((_,a)=>[...m].map((_,b)=>-~a>++b?-~a:b)) // 63

n=>[...(m=Array(n))].map((_,a)=>[...m].map((_,b)=>-~a>++b?-~a:b)) // 65

n=>[...(m=Array(n)).keys()].map(a=>[...m.keys()].map(b=>-~a>++b?-~a:b)) // 71
```

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT0/PsagosVIjTzNWLzexQEMjXqdCJ1HT1i4Rxq0EcnTrKuy0tSvtgbRVpabm/@T8vOL8nFS9nPx0jTQNC6AIAA)

Comment: [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5aT0/PsagosVIjTzNWLzexQEMjXqdCJ1HT1i4Rxq0EcirsKrW17XXrKqwqNTX/J@fnFefnpOrl5KdrpGlYAEUA) (based on Shaggy's version)

Comment: Damn, @Arnauld, how'd I miss that? I blame being back behind my bar for the first time in 6 months; I'm clearly out of practice at "bar-golfing"!

Comment: [55](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEADA7@xiSscINHpJLKVhmIpG6KWvW3ScOeimvCYbL@7DppuRzUs1p0QVPApjnYMexUkRoHalI5SKfi5SFVUZm/hTxorY1uBzcFq4sIOB4ZsX)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 65 bytes

```c
i,j;f(n){for(i=1;n/i;)printf(j/n?j=!++i,"%d\n":"%d ",i>++j?i:j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxCoAwDADAWV9RC0JCK@LgYlA/4iKVSgJGKW7i26vTLReaPYSc2QtFUHzimYDHjrRlwiux3hGk1VnGyjn2tt4WtcOPsZ4n52TmQZDe/E9zrKyA5imLCD1S@eYP)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 35 bytes

```ruby
->x{(1..x).map{|y|[y]*y+[*y+1..x]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iWsNQT69CUy83saC6prImujJWq1I7GohBwrG1tf81jPT0DA2gCipqChTSooHi/wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
Lã€àsä
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5/DiR01rDi8oPrzk/6Hd/y0A) Outputs as a 2D list. Link includes a footer to format the output.

```
Lã€àsä  # full program
  €     # list of...
   à    # maximum...
  €     # s...
   à    # of...
  €     # each element of...
 ã      # list of distinct combinations of two elements in...
L       # [1, 2, 3, ...,
        # ..., implicit input...
L       # ]...
 ã      # repeated twice...
     ä  # split into pieces of length...
    s   # implicit input
        # implicit output
```

Comment: [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx@XcFt//h3b/twAA). (I'm honestly surprised `M` works here tbh. ;p)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
f n=(<$>[1..n]).max<$>[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hz1bDRsUu2lBPLy9WUy83sQLO@5@bmJmnYKuQm1jgq1BQlJlXoqCikKZg@v9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Generates each row by taking the max of each element of `[1..n]` and a fixed value equal to the row number.

```hs
map(max 3)[1,2,3,4,5] = [3,3,3,4,5]
```

We use `<$>` as an infix synonym for `map`.

It would be nice to reuse the `<$>[1..n]`, but it runs into type-checking issues

**26 bytes, doesn't work**

```hs
f n|q<-(<$>[1..n])=q$q.max
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hr6bQRlfDRsUu2lBPLy9W07ZQpVAvN7Hif25iZp6CrUJuYoGvQkFRZl6JgopCmoLp/3/JaTmJ6cX/dZMLCgA)

If a 1D output is allowed, we can do:

**25 bytes**

```hs
f n=max<$>[1..n]<*>[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzzY3scJGxS7aUE8vL9ZGC8r4n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCikKZg@v9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda n:[print(*(max(y,x)+1 for y in range(n))) for x in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKrqgKDOvRENLIzexQqNSp0JT21AhLb9IoVIhM0@hKDEvPVUjT1NTEyxWgSwW@z9Nw0LzPwA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>51</s> 49 bytes

```python
lambda n:mgrid[:n,:n].max(0)+1
from numpy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKje9KDMl2ipPxyovVi83sULDQFPbkCutKD9XIa80t6BSITO3IL@oROt/QVFmXolGmoaFpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL (277 bytes)

Not sure how inputs are handled in SQL but my first declared parameter is the input. I also can't get an online T-SQL compiler that runs this. But this will run in your SSMS just fine.

```
DECLARE @a int = 7DECLARE @ int=1DECLARE @c int=1DECLARE @b nvarchar(max)='SELECT'WHILE @<=@a BEGIN
SET @c=1WHILE @c<=@a BEGIN
SET @b+=IIF(@c=1,'',',')+STR(IIF(@c<@,@,@c))+'AS['+STR(@c)+']'SET @c+=1
END
SET @b+=IIF(@<@a,'UNION ALL SELECT','')SET @+=1
END
EXEC sp_executesql @b;
```

It's a naive approach with nothing special, except that it dynamically builds up a query.

The query it generates is:

```
SELECT         1AS[         1],         2AS[         2],         3AS[         3]UNION ALL SELECT         2AS[         1],         2AS[         2],         3AS[         3]UNION ALL SELECT         3AS[         1],         3AS[         2],         3AS[         3]
```

Comment: This works, or you can take SQL input [from a pre-existing table](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Answer (score 2):

## [Regenerate](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Regenerate), 80 bytes

```
((${$2+1}|1)( $2){$2-1}( ${$4+1}{1-$4/$~1}| ${$2+1}{1-$2/$~1}){$~1-$2+1}\n){$~1}
```

Takes the argument from the command-line. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/regenerate)

#### Explanation

(Spaces are replaced with underscores to improve visibility.)

Each line is generated in three parts. Top-level structure:

```
(                           )       Group 1: a line of output
 (...)                               Group 2: the first digit
      (...){...}                     Group 3: repetitions of the first digit
                (...){...}           Group 4: count up to N
                          \n         Add a newline
                             {$~1}  Repeat, generating N lines
```

Group 2, the first digit on each line:

```
(         )
 ${$2+1}     Add 1 to the previous value of group 2
        |    Or, if group 2 has not been previously matched...
         1   Use 1
```

Group 3, the rest of the digits on the line that are identical to the first number:

```
(_$2)        The most recent value of group 2 (with a space in front of it)
     {$2-1}  repeated (group 2) - 1 times
```

Group 4, the remaining numbers on the line, starting with (group 2) + 1 and counting up to N:

```
( ${$4+1}{1-$4/$~1}| ${$2+1}{1-$2/$~1}){$~1-$2+1}
(                                     )
 _                                                 Space
  ${$4+1}                                          Previous value of group 4, plus 1
         {        }                                Repeat the value this many times:
            $4/$~1                                  1 if group 4 == N, 0 otherwise
          1-                                        Subtract from 1: 1 -> 0 and 0 -> 1
                                                   So if the new value would have been N+1,
                                                   it instead becomes empty string
                   |                               If the previous value of group 4 was not
                                                   a number, the arithmetic fails, and we
                                                   instead use...
                    _                              Space
                     ${$2+1}                       Last value of group 2, plus 1
                            {1-$2/$~1}             Repeat 0 times if group 2 == N
                                       {        }  Repeat the above
                                        $~1-$2+1   N - (group 2) + 1 times
```

#### Worked example

Suppose the input is 3.

**Line 1:**

- Group 2: not previously matched, so `1`
- Group 3:  `1` repeated `1-1` = 0 times, so empty string
- Group 4 is repeated `3-1+1` = 3 times:

  1. Group 4 not previously matched, so   followed by `2` repeated `1-1/3` = 1 time (the division is integer division)
  2. Previous value of group 4 is  `2`, so   followed by `3` repeated `1-2/3` = 1 time
  3. Previous value of group 4 is  `3`, so   followed by `4` repeated `1-3/3` = 0 times

Result: `1 2 3`

**Line 2:**

- Group 2: previous value is `1`, so `2`
- Group 3:  `2` repeated `2-1` = 1 time
- Group 4 is repeated `3-2+1` = 2 times:

  1. Previous value of group 4 is  , which is not a number, so   followed by `3` repeated `1-2/3` = 1 time
  2. Previous value of group 4 is  `3`, so   followed by `4` repeated `1-3/3` = 0 times

Result: `2 2 3`

**Line 3:**

- Group 2: previous value is `2`, so `3`
- Group 3:  `3` repeated `3-1` = 2 times
- Group 4 is repeated `3-3+1` = 1 time:

  1. Previous value of group 4 is  , which is not a number, so   followed by `4` repeated `1-3/3` = 0 times

Result: `3 3 3`

Answer (score 2):

## Nim, <s>138</s> 122 bytes

```
proc x(i:int)=
  for x in 1..i:
    for j in 1..x:stdout.write($x&" ")
    for j in x+1..i:stdout.write($j&" ")
    echo()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [ayr](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/ayr), 5 bytes

```
^:\`~
```

## Explained

```
    ~  One-range to N
   `   Commute (copy arg to make next symbol dyadic)
  \    Table
^:      Of maxes
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, <s>45</s> 44 bytes

<sup>Saved 1 bytes thanks to [Taylor Raine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229414/generate-this-number-table/243908?noredirect=1#comment548864_243908) because of course. At least now it's my [favorite number](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48100/very-simple-triangles/48101#comment113015_48101) of bytes.</sup>

```
[A1].Resize([A1],[A1])="=Max(Row(),Column())"
```

Input is in the cell `A1` of the active sheet. Program is run from the immediate window. It works by writing a formula into a range of cells. This will also overwrite the input cell with a formula.

[image: Example5]

[image: Example8]

Comment: You can drop a byte by removing the terminal `"`

Comment: @TaylorRaine I was specifically thinking of you when I figured out I could drop `.Formula` after the resize and I was so excited to have an answer where you wouldn't be able to point out what should have been an obvious optimization. One day, Taylor. One day...

Comment: XD You'll get there, I'm sure of it! And it's not like I don't make those same mistakes myself, lol :P

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 75 bytes

Not the best JS solution for a string output, but really close!

I tried to gain bytes by parsing only a single one-dimensional array, but lost some bytes in calculations, and i don't find how to shorten it further.

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n*n)].map((_,i)=>Math.max(i%n,i/n|0)+1+(++i%n?' ':`
`)).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7RTsIwFIbv9xQnSwytm1UYg4WkEB/AJ3CGNqNgyTxbumIw8dY7H0FfjheZDaMDQ/40Pedr@51u5btsCqNre4fVSrVr3iKfPzPGHo2RHwRvkb6wN1kTsow15fMnaV9dvyf6BmN9j58PNBpGJIpcvxjAYCYCQSnbVhqFaGXTKGM50VjvbKz2tSqsWsVGNbvS8nXHqdMWFTZVqVhZbQg5HXPuHyzCw89XjuEsPPx@u51G3RUaBN0EAikAxG6JIYwggTGkOY7OZQKJL8fQxZUpnJKjANq7sisXTGAK2YXRg97rQW/3oJ/hwQTOOYIpXMaBDP7l@Ln2Dw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 bytes

```perl
//,say map{$",$_<$'?$':$_}@;for@;=1..<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fX6c4sVIhN7GgWkVJRyXeRkXdXkXdSiW@1sE6Lb/IwdrWUE/Pxu7/f4t/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), 11 bytes

```
{(⍳⍵)∘.⌈⍳⍵}
```

Anonymous prefix function

-2 bytes thanks to @Adam in chat

Comment: You can use `∘.⌈⍨⍳⍵` instead of `(⍳⍵)∘.⌈⍳⍵`, buuut then it's the same as Adam's answer :/

Comment: @user thanks but Adam already ninja'd the suggestion :P (in chat)

Comment: Oh, I see. You don't need the `f←`, by the way.

Comment: @user oh sorry (filler)

Comment: How to get to a solution as shot as, but different from, mine: Notice that you have two "outer" function applications (`⍳` and `⍳`), with their results being the arguments to an "inner" dyadic function `∘.⌈`. This is perfect for a [fork](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Tacit_programming#Forks): `⍳∘.⌈⍳`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 15 bytes

```
ɾƛnS:I*fvI⁰ɾnȯJ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%C6%9BnS%3AI*fvI%E2%81%B0%C9%BEn%C8%AFJ&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

Wish if we had maximum table....

Answer (score 1):

## Posix SH + sed, <s>99</s> <s>97</s> 96 bytes

```bash
seq -s\  $1|sed -nE ':t
p
s/((.)( \2)*) (.)/\1=\4/
/(.)=\1/q
:r
s/ ?(.)=(.)/=\2 \2/
tr
s/=//
tt'
```

or, 99 bytes with looping (ugh):

```
seq -s\  $1|sed -nE ':t
p
s/(.) /\1=/
:l
s/(.)=\1 ?/\1 \1=/
tl
:r
s/ ?(.)=(.)/=\2 \2/
tr
s/^=//
tt'
```

With an earlier gnu sed version, `:t` and `tt` can be replaced with `:` and `t`, respectively, saving two bytes for each solution (I think).

Takes input in `$1`. Outputs exactly as in the question (but with a trailing newline I think).

### Explanation

```bash
seq -s\  $1       \  # Collect the numbers 1..$1 with space as
                  \  # the -separator.
  |sed -nE '...'     # Replace it. The -E is for -Extended Regular
                     # Expressions, which allow less escaping.
                     # The -n is for -no printing by default.
```

```perl
:t                          # Label for "t"op.
p                           # "p"rint the line.
s/((.)( \2)*) (.)/\1=\4/    # Mark the end of the first run of
                            # equal elements followed by a number.
                            #    4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 9
                            # => 4 4 4 4=5 6 7 8 9
                            #    9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
                            # => 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9=9
/(.)=\1/q                   # If the marked element and its successor
                            # are the same (like in the example above
                            # with all nines), "q"uit, don't process
                            # any more lines.
:r                          # Start "r"eplacement loop.
s/ ?(.)=(.)/=\2 \2/         # For any characters a, b, replace a=b
                            # with =b b. examples:
                            #    4 4 4 4=5 6 7 8 9
                            # => 4 4 4=5 5 6 7 8 9
                            # => 4 4=5 5 5 6 7 8 9
tr                          # "t"est if there was a replacement made.
                            # if there was, do another replacement
                            # loop iteration.
s/=//                       # At this point, the cursor must have
                            # reached the beginning of the line
                            # so no replacement could be made.
                            # Remove the =
tt                          # Go to the top again, where this row
                            # will be printed, and a new one will be
                            # started.
```

Comment: If you're OK with using the [GNU exec extension to sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-GNU-extensions_002c-subprocesses), then you can dispense with sh and [do this all in sed](https://tio.run/##FYo5DoAwDAR7v8IVSpDICgQNUkTFL1ySgobLvB/jdLM7o2UzUyRoublTEeYGhWa6SBFCioFliG1kR0ifZQTBOUuPm@bHK17qrj7L4DXorXeGg9n0nde7n4dad6w/) for a score of 90

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>75</s></sup> 77 bytes

Added 2 bytes for a bug fix kindly provided by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper).

```c
i;j;k;f(n){for(i=0;n/++i;puts(""))for(j=i,k=0;n/++k;j+=k>=i)printf("%d ",j);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY7BDoIwEETvfMWmiUk3hYhe13L0K7gQTElbXAlgPBB@3dpG9OLBuWx29s1k26LtG@5CsOTIk5GMi7mN0uqSeK@UpeE@T1IIxGQ7bXO/nTw5pX2lLQ6j5dlIsbuAyB3SGuIO18ayxGzJICqGQSaXQcOR4jjBoSRQihHeSNKn6RzxRMbGoqq5ZpEDI3259Cf9pGrW/xSbtuCareHZmr7pplA8Xg)

Comment: The core dump is likely because you didn't provide an argument for `puts()`.

Comment: @dingledooper I'm blind - thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
ＮθＥθ⭆θ⊕⌈⟦ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDN7FAo1BHIbgEyEuHcjzzkotSc1PzSlJTgPIVmbmluRrRmToKObGaIGD9/7/Ff92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ          First input as an integer
   θ        Input
  Ｅ         Map over implicit range (0-indexed)
     θ      Input
    ⭆       Map over implicit range and join
         ι  Outer index
          λ Inner index
       ⌈⟦   Maximum of all of the above
      ⊕     Incremented
            Implicitly print
```

Would be 14 bytes if spacing was desired (13 bytes if a leading space was acceptable).

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 84 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<n*n;)System.out.printf("%d%c",i%n>i/n?i%n+1:i/n+1,++i%n<1?13:32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU49b4NADN35FRYSEhRyzTUbR5KhU4dOGasO14OLTMCHOBOpivjt9Jqmaocstp/9Ptzqs1619WnBfnAjQxuwmBg7YScyjI7EC/GzIz/1zagi02nv4VUjwSUCGKaPDg141hza2WENfbilBx6Rjm/voMejz65UgH9GYGELC612F@vGFIkBt2uFFT2Qyg6fnpteuInFEGzYpnFSJyYuMKEdPtI@9FyWYcplkecBVXIvN@XmKVPzoq5ZwRZ@fEOQVBBoUIFcK/j9BuBuTplQXABm6kayQhvTDJz@re7pKMhuhDmKvsu8fAE)

### Alternative, 84 bytes too

```java
n->{for(int i=1,j=0;i<=n;)System.out.printf("%d%c",i>++j?i:j,(j%=n)<1?13+i-i++:32);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY4xb4NADIV3foWFhAQ6OIVm4yAZOnXolLHqcD1C5Av4EGciVRG/nV7TVO2QxZbt975nqy@6sO15xWF0E4MNs5wZe9nNZBgdyRfiZ0d@Ho6TikyvvYdXjQTXCGCcP3o04FlzaBeHLQzhlh54Qjq9vYOeTj67SQH@gaCDBlYqdtfOTSkSAzZlbpuNwrohlR0@PR8H6WaWYyBxl8ZJm5g4x50Qdo@VzVObNJTV5b7cCixQiGr7lKllVbesgIUfbggqFQiBUEO5UfD7DcDDkCqhOAfM1F3USW3MceT0b/XIR8F2FyxR9F2W9Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
´ṪYḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CWhztXRT7csfj///8WAA)

Outputs as a 2d matrix.

```
´       # argdup: apply a funciton to two copies of the same argument 
 Ṫ      # Ṫable: make a 'multiplication table' ...
  Y     # ... using function Y = maximum of two values
   ḣ    # with (duplicated) argument ḣ = range from 1 to input number
```

[7 bytes](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9odXNr///Ctm13wrThuapZ4bij////OA) - `¶mw´ṪYḣ` - to ouput in the exact same format as the examples in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/) -F, <s>80</s> 69 bytes

```php
for(;++$i<=$argn;)echo str_pad('',$i-1,$i).join(range($i,$argn))."
";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKy1tVUybWxVEovS86w1U5Mz8hWKS4riCxJTNNTVdVQydQ2BhKZeVn5mnkZRYl56qoZKpg5YtaamnhKXkvX//6b/8gtKMvPziv/rugEA)

Quite naive solution, but I think it can be golfed more..

**EDIT:** saved 11 bytes by having a shorter `str_pad` so that the `join(range(` is no longer conditional

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 52 bytes

```python
lambda a="123456789":[a[n]*n+a[n:]for n in range(9)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PycxNyklUSHRVsnQyNjE1MzcwlLJKjoxOi9WK08bSFnFpuUXKeQpZOYpFCXmpadqWGrG/v8PAA)

Comment: It still dosen't take input, please re-read the question and fix it [like this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFLJ9FWydDI2MTUzNzCUskqOjE6L1YrTxtIWcWm5Rcp5Clk5ikUJealp2pkacb@LyjKzCvRSNOw1NT8DwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 26 bytes

```
n->matrix(n,,i,j,max(i,j))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XLjexpCizQiNPRydTJ0snN7FCA0hrav4vKMrMKynQSNOwAHIA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal 2.6.0](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 4 bytes

```
ẊvGẇ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyIiwiIiwi4bqKdkfhuociLCIiLCI1Il0=)

Feels good to have Cartesian product use ranges for numbers now. Posting as a separate answer to emanresuA because it uses features not available in the version they used (haha rewrite go brrr).

### Explained

```
ẊvGẇ
Ẋ    # The Cartesian Product of the ranges [1, input] and [1, input]
 vG  # the maximum of each pair
   ẇ # wrapped to chunks of length input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 12 bytes

```
VSQm?>dNdNSQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyw4MNfeLsUvxS848P9/SwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel (Office 365 Insider Preview), 38 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input \$n\$ from cell `A1` and outputs an \$n\times n\$ [dynamic array](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) to the calling cell.

This solution makes use of the [`=MAKEARRAY()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/makearray-function-b80da5ad-b338-4149-a523-5b221da09097) and [`=LAMBDA()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) functions, which are currently only available via the [Office Insiders](https://insider.office.com/en-us/) program.

```vb
=MakeArray(A1,A1,Lambda(r,c,Max(r,c)))
```

#### Annotated

```vb
=MakeArray(A1,A1,                    ) ' Make an nxn array holding row & col index
                 Lambda(r,c,        )  ' Pass the indices into a function
                            Max(r,c)   ' Take the larger of two at each position
                                       ' Output as nxn dynamic array
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RDȷ§
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJEJUM4JUI3JUMyJUE3JmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9NSZmbGFncz0=)

##### Explanation

```python
RDȷ§  # Implicit input
R     # Push [1..input]
 D    # Duplicate
  ȷ   # Outer product over:
   §  #  Dyadic maximum
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊞↥.+1⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4oqe4oalLisx4oehCgpmIDUKZiA4Cg==)

```
⊞↥.+1⇡
     ⇡  # range
   +1   # increment
  .     # duplicate
⊞↥      # table by maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ǒ∴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCLHkuKItCIsIiIsIjgiXQ==)

> Wish if we had maximum table....

Wish no more!

Quite literally table by maximum

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 16 bytes

```
x=x«y=x²yMS•.p»;
```

### Explaination

```
x=x«y=x²yMS•.p»;
x=               # Set x to the input
  x«          »; # For 1 - x
    y=           # Assign y to the iterator
      x²  S      # Generate a stack from a pair-function
        yM       # The max of y and the current index
           •.p  # Join via spaces, and print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6/7/CtuLQ6kogsanSN/hRwyK9gkO7rf///28JAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 52 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=(i,j)=>i?[...g(i-1,j),j?i<j?j:i:g(n,i)]:[])(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcdJCoAwDADA7yRQC96kGPsQ6UFcSoIkYsXvR@c2srxLW2@@nk5t2/0gV5qgEnAQpInzHGOswF3/P0jmUbIkThU0MJY0FwRFX02bnXs8rcIBA6J/)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,x,a)=>a.map((_,y)=>1+(x+=y>x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NchBCoAgEADA7@ySLXTrskLviIjFNArTsAh9vXXpOLPLI5dJ23m3IS62Oq6B9UhEQ0pSIOBEh5wAs8pKkLX8LB@6BnLDRWdErCaGK3pLPq7goP/mBQ)

From user100752(deleted)'s answer

[Alternate](https://tio.run/##HchBCoAgEADA7@xiSscINHpJLKVhmIpG6KWvW3ScOeimvCYbL@7DppuRzUs1p0QVPApjnYMexUkRoHalI5SKfi5SFVUZm/hTxorY1uBzcFq4sIOB4ZsX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda x:[[i+1]*i+range(i+1,x+1)for i in range(x)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjo6U9swVitTuygxLz1VA8jRqdA21EzLL1LIVMjMU4AIV2jG/i8oyswrUUjTMNXkgjEtNP8DAA)

-2 bytes thanks to dingledooper

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjo6U9swVitTuygxLz1VA8jRqdA21EzLL1LIVMjMU4AIV2jG/i8oyswrUUjTMNXkgjEtNP8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 85 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...(A=Array)(n)].map((_,i)=>[...A(i++).fill(i),...[...A(n-i+1)].map((u,j)=>i+j)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCoMwEEbh68xP4kB33aSQc4hIsEYmxIlEW@jpU0Hcfu@l8A37VGU7Oi3vuUXX1L16ZibvfK3hB1IMvIaNaLSCK3oSY8BRciaBPeVS7cQ87v1j07mLSRjQpqJ7yTPnslCkJ9D@)

In the form of an array. Since JS doesn't have the convenient `list.__mul__` and `list.__add__` operations, this takes up quite some space.

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i=0)=>n-i?`${i+1} `.repeat(i)+[...Array(n-i++)].map((_,j)=>i+j).join` `+`
`+f(n,i):''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEEDRvafoQugM0w66EyGK5xBxQk1kQpuEtAginj3W/X8/2Jedh6J56WN6uFq9gdip2aE5xV7Psv0o7b@NcHHZ2QUU6crMl1LsG9aCCG882Qxw78KKlAJySBqlEZKNkP//8Ni2dUhxTqPjMT3BwwGx/gA)

As a string.

---

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 36 bytes

```arturo
$[n][map 1..n'x[++repeat x x-1x..n]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?bMoQcT)

```
$[n][               ; a function taking an argument n
  map 1..n'x[       ; map over the range 1..n; assign current value to x
    ++              ; append
    repeat x x-1    ; a block containing x x-1 times
    x..n            ; the range x..n
  ]                 ; end map
]                   ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0 -na`, 37 bytes

```perl
$,=$";say+($_)x$_,$_+1.."@F"for 1..$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJCw9JFwiO3NheSsoJF8peCRfLCRfKzEuLlwiQEZcImZvciAxLi4kXyIsImFyZ3MiOiItTTUuMTAuMFxuLW5hIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIxXG41XG44In0=)