# Generate this string table

Tags: code-golf, string, matrix

For the given string `s`, generate generate a table like below.

```
Input:abcd
Output:
abcd
bbcd
cccd
dddd

Input:Hello, world!
Output:
Hello, world!
eello, world!
llllo, world!
llllo, world!
ooooo, world!
,,,,,, world!
       world!
wwwwwwwworld!
ooooooooorld!
rrrrrrrrrrld!
llllllllllld!
dddddddddddd!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Trailing whitespace allowed.
This is a code-golf challenge so the shortest solution wins.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/print-output-the-l-phabet), [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/229414/generate-this-number-table)

Comment: I'd lean towards it being too close a duplicate of the linked challenges... was there a discussion on the Sandbox determining otherwise?

Comment: It kind of combines the two related challenges.

Comment: @UnrelatedString it lived in the sandbox for 1 hour, so, no.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 12 bytes

Anonymous prefix lambda.

```apl
{⍵[∘.⌈⍨⍳≢⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79boRx0z9B71dDzqXfGod/OjzkVAsdja/2mP2iY86u171NX8qHfNo94th9YbP2qb@KhvanCQM5AM8fAM/p@moJ6YlJyizgVkeKTm5OSX6yiU5xflpCiqAwA)

`{`…`}` "dfn"; argument is `⍵`

`⍵[`…`]` index into characters using the array:

`≢⍵` tally of characters

`⍳` indices of array of that length

`∘.⌈⍨` maximum-table using that both going down and across

Comment: I came up with the same in J, which beats APL by 1 byte this time: `{~>./~@i.@#`

Comment: @Jonah Yeah, APL is missing `{` from. I am lobbying for its addition as `⊇` so we can write `∘.⌈⍨⍤⍳⍤≢⊇⊢` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HHDL1HPR2Pelc86l3yqHcziOxc9Kir/VHXov9pj9omPOrte9TV/Kh3zaPeLYfWGz9qm/iob2pwkDOQDPHwDP6fpqCemJScos4FZHik5uTkl@solOcX5aQoqgMA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 9 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

Tacit prefix port of [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243945/43319)

```
⌈⌜˜∘↕∘≠⊸⊏
```

`⌈` maximum-

`⌜` table

`˜` of self

`∘` of

`↕` the indices

`∘`

`≠` the string length

`⊸⊏` selects characters from that tring

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RuKGkOKMiOKMnMuc4oiY4oaV4oiY4omg4oq44oqPCkbCqCJhYmNkIuKAvyJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhIg==)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
{x@i|\i:!#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJyFkbFugzAURff3FYZ2SKQQSy1LYenYTv2ANFKMMWDFxaltFKI0/fbGBBCPDL3T9ZGfDcdFcm5f5c+nTIKH9gLgkvPj5vRrkoIQ0qY7vU8Xu4JJlbbpKTXL7QXcJmQZz0Mgi6GQMBsK59dCfMuvCZdb8ANvQim9IkdtVB50k3NCQnFHlPqfaB9EVl2mhNwyIcc+s3N8RmLGTG/v05N8khsJpul+n0Ll3MEmlHKdi1KrYm0d43vR8orVpVhz/UW/G2Gd1LWlT/HzSxzTUtTCMCciV0kbWWdkXUaOZUoAvNeHxiXePXw0znfoFv4RwD8A+O8Z9iHT4wCmyD0gy7MV8g3INSDPgBwD8gvILSCvgJwC8vkHcHHRzQ==)

A port of [@Adám's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/243945/98547), using a trick with a seeded scan instead of an each-right or each-left.

- `i:!#x` generate list of indices of the input `x`, storing in `i`
- `i|\i` set up a scan, seeded with `i`, run over each value in `i`. this is equivalent to, but one byte shorter, than `i|/:i` or `i|\:i`
- `x@` index back into the input, implicitly returning

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda s:[s[l]*l+s[l:]for l in range(len(s))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCsIwEITvfYo1l/zYXvQWqGffofaQ2kQLa1KSBRHx2WPTgjiXZYf5dmd@0T34Y3btJaN5DKOBpLvUYa9wvwzduxABYfIQjb9ZgdaLJGWfySZK0IJgZriOrAZ2toihhmeIOO6YrApJhVyjuoJFc5w8CcfZmz4MmhNwufrlkhO0Lb@XSW95lH8wb7gqLUiqg8xf)

Inputs a string.
Returns a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->s{r=0;s.chars.map{|c|s[0,r+=1]=c*r;s.b}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664usjWwLpYLzkjsahYLzexoLomuaY42kCnSNvWMNY2WasIKJlUW/u/oLSkWCEtWskxL0UhUSG5KjU5QyE/L1WhJD9fKfY/AA)