# Loves me, loves me not

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity

## [Loves me, Loves me not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_loves_me..._he_loves_me_not)

This simple kids' game is old, but still popular. Since we are living in 21st century now, let's digitize it!

## Specification

Program must take no input, unless you are using a language that can't generate random seed - in that case you are allowed to take the seed as an input. Your task is to write a program that will output randomly a total of 3 to 20 lines inclusive: "Loves me..." and "Loves me not..." in turns, as in the game (and one additional line; keep reading).

However, there are some restrictions. Each line should be followed by newline. The first line must be "Loves me...". The last line (either "Loves me" or "Loves me not") should end with exclamation mark or a single dot, respectively. After the last line, you need to output either a heart( `<3` ) or a broken heart ( `</3` ) in the new line, depending whether "Loves me!" or "Loves me not." was the last sentence.

Trailing whitespace are allowed.

## Example Output

Output:

> Loves me...
> Loves me not...
> Loves me...
> Loves me not...
> Loves me!
> <3

Another output:

> Loves me...
> Loves me not...
> Loves me...
> Loves me not.
> </3

### This is the [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest entry wins!

Also, my first challenge :) Good luck!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the distribution of the number of lines, i.e., should it be uniformly random, or is it enough that all lengths between 3 and 20 have a positive probability?

Comment: I didn't think about this, but I'd say that any distribution is fine - so they **don't** have to be uniformly random.

Comment: Is it 3 to 20 (`[3, 20)`) or 3 up to including 20 (`[3, 20]`)?

Comment: @orlp Edited to adress that concern. 3 is minimum, 20 is maximum. So 20 lines is ok, but no 21.

Comment: @MatthewRock What if the language we want to use can't seed a random number on their own? Can the user supply a random seed?

Comment: @minxomat I'd prefer it to be random-random, so no user should generate randomness. Couldn't you get time or anything similar?

Comment: @minxomat Are you trying to do this in Brainf*** or what?

Comment: @MatthewRock No. There are a few languages that do not have support for timers. I'd like to require a seed from the user. I still have to implement a proper PRNG, so the challenge isn't easier for me.

Comment: @minxomat what language is it?

Comment: @MatthewRock let him take the seed as a input.

Comment: @minxomat Whatever, it's just a game. Go on, changed the rules.

Comment: I don't think this fits with [kolmogorov-complexity] if you can have two different outputs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Pyth, <strike>54</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>51</strike> <strike>50</strike> 48 bytes

```
pj+*3\.bm+W~!Z"Loves me"" not"+3O18@".!"Z%hZ"</3
```

Comment: `%2tWZ"<</33` for the heart printing saves 1. Not convinced this is the best way though.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Made it save two.

Comment: [Merging the last two strings together](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bj%22...%0A%22m%2BW~%21Z%22Loves+me%22%22+not%22%2B3O17%252tWZ%22.%21%0A%0A%3C%3C%2F33&debug=1) saves another one, but I had to switch back to my `%`.

Comment: `@".!"Z%hZ"</3` saves two bytes

Comment: Since there has been no entry for few days, I'm accepting this answer. Congratulations!

Answer (score 23):

## CJam, <s>53</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*Thanks to Dennis for saving 1 byte.*

```
Imr3+{"Loves me"X!:X" not"*'.3*N}*&"!."X=N'<'/X*3
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Imr3%2B%7B%22Loves%20me%22X!%3AX%22%20not%22*'.3*N%7D*%26%22!.%22X%3DN'%3C'%2FX*3)

### Explanation

The code just dumps the string in bits and pieces onto the stack, which is printed automatically at the end of the program:

```
Imr3+         e# Generate a random number in [3,20]
{             e# Execute this block that many times.
  "Loves me"  e#   Push "Loves me", we always need that.
  X!:X        e#   Toggle X (initially 1) between 0 and 1 and leave it on the stack.
  " not"*     e#   Repeat " not" that many times, removing it on every other line.
  '.3*N       e#   Push "..." and a newline.
}*
&             e# Set intersection of "..." and newline, turning them into an empty array.
"!."X=        e# Select "!" or "." based on the last value of X.
N'<           e# Push a newline and "<".
'/X*          e# Include "/" or not depending on the last value of X.
3             e# Push a 3.
```

Comment: one could imagine CJam would've been developed exclusively for code-golf ^^

Comment: @larkey but it is...

Comment: @larkey CJam is derived from GolfScript, and GolfScript (as its name implies) _is_ designed for golfing.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it was ment a bit tongue-in-cheek ;-)

Answer (score 17):

## Brainfuck, 2766 bytes (currently invalid)

Just because. I'll add an ungolfed version later.

#### Code

```
>+<+[>[>[-]+<-]>[<+>>+[->,----------[<+>[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>[>+<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<-]]<]<-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[>[-]+<-]>[<+>>>>>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>-]>[<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<+++++++[<+++++++++++>-]<[<<[>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<+>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[>>>>>>>>+[<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>-]<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]+<[>-<[-]]>[>>>>>+<<<<<-]<<-]<-]++++++[>++++++++<-]>-[<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<+<-]>[<+>-]>-]<<<[-]>[-]+++++[<+++++>-]<[>>>>>>>>>>>+[<<<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<-]+<[>-<[-]]>[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]<<-]++++++[>>>>>>>>>>+++++++++<<<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>>[<<+<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[-]>[<+<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>[-]++++++++++++++++++++<<[<<<+>>>-]>>[<<<<<<<<+>+<<+>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<-]>>[>>[<+<<<+>>>>-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]+>>>[<<->>>-<<<<->>>[-]]<<<[>>[-]+<<-]>>-]>>[>>>-<<<[-]]<<<[-]>>>>>>>>[-]<[>+<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>>>>[-]+++<<<[<<<<<+>>>>>-]>>>[<<<<<<<<<<<+>+<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<-]>>[>>[<+<<<+>>>>-]<<<<[>>>>+<<<<-]+>>>[<<->>>-<<<<->>>[-]]<<<[>>[-]+<<-]>>-]<[>>>>>>>>-<<<<<<<<[-]]>>>[-]>>>[<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>-<<<<<<<[-]]>>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<<+>+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]<[>>>>>>>[-]-<<<<<<<[-]]>>>>>>>[>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>>[-]]<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[>[-]+<-]>[<+>>+++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++>+++>++++<<<<<-]>-.>+.+++++++.>++.<---.>>-.<<------.>.>>++...[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<++++++++++.[-]>>>>>>>[-]>[<+<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>->[-]<[>+<-][-]>[<+<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>[-]<<[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]->>[<<<<<<<<-<+>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<-]>[>>>>>>+<<<<<<[-]]<->>>>>>>[<<<<<<<->>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>>[-]]<<<<<<<<-]<[>[-]+<-]>[<+>>++++++[>++++++++++<-]>.---------.[-]<<<-<->>-]>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>[<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<[>[-]+<-]>[<+>>+++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++++++++>+++>++++<<<<<-]>-.>+.+++++++.>++.<---.>>-.<<------.>.>.<<+.+.+++++.>>>++...[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<[-]<++++++++++.[-]>>>>>>>[-]>[<+<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>->[-]<[>+<-][-]>[<+<<<<<<<+>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>>>[-]<<[<<<<<<+>>>>>>-]->>[<<<<<<<<-<+>>>>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<-]>[>>>>>>+<<<<<<[-]]<->>>>>>>[<<<<<<<->>>>>>>-]<<<<<<<[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<-]>>>>>>>[>>>>>>>+<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<->>>>>>>>>[-]]<<<<<<<<-]<[>[-]+<-]>[<+>>++++++[>++++++++++<-]>.-------------.++++.<<<<->>-]<<]
```

#### Pseudocode

```
loop
    get a random byte
until random byte is >2 and <21

point to byte
[
    output "Loves me..."
    decrease byte by 1
    if byte is 0
        output "<3"
        exit
    eif
    output "Loves me not..."
    decrease byte by 1
]
output "</3"
```

#### Sample

When run, the program enters an interactive session waiting for input. Input should be a number. This number is used as a seed.

**Seed: 1 (random number is 5, takes 218,168,042 operations)**

```
1              
Loves me...    
Loves me not...
Loves me...    
Loves me not...
Loves me...    
<3
```

**Seed: 3 (random number is 20, takes 463,253,048 operations)**

```
3
Loves me...
Loves me not...
(...)
Loves me...
Loves me not...
</3
```

I'd suggest that you do not seed with `6`, as it takes `2,105,900,375` iterations to compute the result :).

#### Compiling / Running

You need a fast interpreter for this. No online interpreter I've tested could handle the execution speed. The ips (iterations per second) should be more than `100,000,000`. So I came up with another solution.

This is a Brainfuck to C compiler written in Brainfuck. You can use any online interpreter to transpile my code to pure C. I suggest using [brainfuck.tk](http://brainfuck.tk). Paste my code in the stdin input, past this code in the code input:

```
+++[>+++++<-]>>+<[>>++++>++>+++++>+++++>+>>+<++[++<]>---]>++++.>>>.+++++.>------.<--.+++++++++.>+.+.<<<<---.[>]<<.<<<.-------.>++++.<+++++.+.>-----.>+.<++++.>>++.>-----.<<<-----.+++++.-------.<--.<<<.>>>.<<+.>------.-..--.+++.-----<++.<--[>+<-]>>>>>--.--.<++++.>>-.<<<.>>>--.>.<<<<-----.>----.++++++++.----<+.+++++++++>>--.+.++<<<<.[>]<.>>,[>>+++[<+++++++>-]<[<[-[-<]]>>[>]<-]<[<+++++>-[<+++>-[<-->-[<+++>-[<++++[>[->>]<[>>]<<-]>[<+++>-[<--->-[<++++>-[<+++[>[-[-[-[->>]]]]<[>>]<<-]>[<+>-[<->-[<++>-[<[-]>-]]]]]]]]]]]]]<[-[-[>+<-]>]<[<<<<.>+++.+.+++.-------.>---.++.<.>-.++<<<<.[>]>>>>>>>>>]<[[<]>++.--[>]>>>>>>>>]<[<<++..-->>>>>>]<[<<..>>>>>]<[<<..-.+>>>>]<[<<++..---.+>>>]<[<<<.>>.>>>>>]<[<<<<-----.+++++>.----.+++.+>---.<<<-.[>]>]<[<<<<.-----.>++++.<++.+++>----.>---.<<<.-[>]]<[<<<<<----.>>.<<.+++++.>>>+.++>.>>]<.>]>,]<<<<<.<+.>++++.<----.>>---.<<<-.>>>+.>.>.[<]>++.[>]<.>[.---->.---,....]
```

Download the source and compile it:

```
gcc.exe -c main.c -o main.o
gcc.exe main.o -o loveme.exe
```

You can also run a copy of the C code online here: [via. CodingGround](http://goo.gl/PQ5kBY).

#### Optimizations

There is still some work to do, but the cell re-use is almost optimal.

#### Remarks

You can use words or phrases as a seed:

```
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
<3
```

Comment: +1 for having the audacity to write a PRNG in Brainfuck ...

Comment: @TimmyD There are better ways to write PRNGs in BF, but most of them are time based (run the program, and stop execution at some point, then read memory), but that would require user interaction and two separate programs, which is against the rules.

Comment: Nice pseudocode. More people should do that, especially since half the golfing languages are basically unreadable if you don't know them.

Comment: Unfortunately your output is wrong. Last "Loves me" should end with an exclamation point(so, "Loves me!"), and "Loves me not" should end with **single** dot("Loves me not.").

Comment: @MatthewRock Will fix.

Comment: Can we have some pseudocode of the RNG?

Comment: Link is borked.

Answer (score 7):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>119</s> <s>104</s> <s>99</s> 98 bytes

```
for(i=new Date%18+3,s=i&1?`!
<3`:`.
</3`;i--;)s=`...
Loves me`+(i&1?' not':'')+s
alert(s.slice(4))
```

Comment: Good one! It may be shorter to use string concatenation for creating the heart, and possibly in the creation of each line. Mind if I use the `new Date` trick in my answer?

Comment: @ETHproductions Go for it, so long as you're fine with me using those hearts haha (and why didn't I use alert... for some reason I convinced myself arrow functions would be shorter, but needing return negates that...). I actually just got it down to 104 now with some other tricks as well =)

Comment: Dang... nice job :) I keep rearranging mine, but always end up at 104.

Comment: The breakthrough for me was combining the length/iteration variable by concatenating backwards, and defining the hearts in the initialization. I tried it a while back with little savings, but your heart simplification made it much more efficient.

Comment: Wait a minute... Trying this, I get `Loves me not... Loves me... Loves me not! <3` and `Loves me not... Loves me... Loves me not... Loves me. </3`. I think you'll have to change one of the conditionals to fix this. EDIT: Oh, just switch the `''` and `' not'` in the fourth line.

Comment: @ETHproductions Seems to reverse on me every time I touch anything to do with that iterator haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 147

```
from random import*;t=randint(3,20)
print"\n".join("LLoovveess  mmee  n o t"[i%2::2].strip()+"..."*(i<t-1)for i in range(t))+"!.\n\n<<3/ 3"[t%2::2]
```

Uses the `from random import*` instead of `import random` and `randint` instead of `randrange` to save a few bytes. There's probably some bytes left to golf out.

Comment: The alternation `"LLoovveess  mmee  n o t"[i%2::2].strip()` seems needlessly complicated. Can't you just do `"Loves me"+~i%2*" not"`?

Comment: Even `["Loves me","Loves me not"][i%2]` is more optimal, since you're now wasting chars on `.strip()` and a couple of spaces. But yes, use xnor's code

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>110</s> 102 bytes

```
a='';for(i=j=new Date%18+3;i--;)a+='Loves me'+(j-i&1?'':' not')+(i?`...
`:j&1?`!
<3`:`.
</3`);alert(a)
```

This was a short but fun little challenge. It may be possible to shorten more. Thanks to Mwr247 for some byte-saving tricks!

Alternate version using `repeat()`, 105 bytes:

```
a='';for(i=j=new Date%18+3;i;)a+='Loves me'+' not'.repeat(j-i--&1)+(i?`...
`:j&1?`!
<3`:`.
</3`);alert(a)
```

Darn JS 5+-char built-in names. Oh well. Suggestions welcome!

Comment: Impressive condensing. I'm curious though, why the `18+3|0`?

Comment: @Mwr247 Oh, duh, that was from when I used `Math.random()`. Guess it's not necessary now.

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 76 bytes

```perl
print"...
"x!!$_,"Loves me"," not"x$|--for 0..2+rand 18;say$|?"!
<3":".
</3"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHRCoIwFAbg@z3F9rO73GkmQqTQC9QzhOAEoXbGNsTAZ@/0fSnkdy@S8horiEhhN8a@Gjx4C0V/AhroyBW7PZxbOGtPdDnlKc66vQ5l@trjDqPGDjeQGs8dRH6c6sqxiHv21Hryfw)

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 91 bytes

```
(n=3+rand(18)).times{|i|puts"Loves me"+[""," not"][i%2]+(i<n-1?"...":i%2>0?".
</3":"!
<3")}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Common Lisp <s>106</s> 104 bytes

```
(format t"~{Loves me~[ not~]~#[~:*~[.~%</~;!~%<~]3~:;...~]~%~}"(subseq'#1=(1 0 . #1#)0(+ 3(random 18))))
```

This only works on lisps that don't check for a proper sequence (e.g. cmucl, sbcl, clisp) ccl will check for circularity and error out on default safety level.  ecl will loop forever.

### Explanation:

`#1=(1 0 . #1#)` generates a circular list containing `1` and `0` and `subseq` is used to make a list of length [3,20] (this is the only non-portable part, as `subseq` is only required by the standard to work on proper (i.e. non-circular) lists).

Our format is now operating on a list of `1 0 1 0...` of length [3,20]

#### Explanation of `format` directives:

`~{` iterates over this list

`~[` followed by any number of `~;` and terminated with `~]` will select the Nth item, based on the value of the format argument.   This is used here so that the first item in a `~[` will be the "loves me not" case and the second one the "loves me" case.  Note that with `~[` a separator of `~:;` selects a default case.

`~#[` works like `~[` except the argument is the number of remaining arguments.  0 remaining arguments means we are at the end, the default case is to print `...`

`~:*` backs up the argument list one position, which allows us to print the correct trailer.

Comment: This was a group effort by the #lisp IRC channel.  Many thanks to phf for the clever iterative format-string and the subseq hack.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>161</s> <s>159</s> <s>156</s> 144 bytes

```
from random import*;a=randrange(3,21)
for i in range(a):print'Loves me'+i%2*' not'+('...'if i!=a-1 else'.'if i%2 else'!')
print['<3','</3'][i%2]
```

It's 39 bytes just to get the random number.

A big thank you to [muddyfish](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32686/muddyfish), [fryamtheeggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman), and [orlp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4162/orlp) for their help.

## [PYG](https://gist.github.com/Celeo/b6ba14082ae6677b3c75), 109 bytes

```
a=RR(3,21)
for i in R(a):P('Loves me'+i%2*' not'+('...'if i!=a-1 else'.'if i%2 else'!'))
P(['<3','</3'][i%2])
```

Comment: You can do the range statement in a single line. you can also do `import random as r`

Comment: you can also put the contents of the last print statement onto the line above.

Comment: I think you can change `print'</3'if i%2 else'<3'` to `print['<3','</3'][i%2]` to save 3 bytes.

Comment: Yes indeed I can; thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, `import random as r;a=r.randrange(3,21)` and `import random;a=random.randrange(3,21)` are the same length.

Comment: [Many standard golfs](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#from%20random%20import%2a%0Aa%3Drandrange%283%2C21%29%0Afor%20i%20in%20range%28a%29%3Aprint%27Loves%20me%27%2Bi%252%2a%27%20not%27%2B%28%27.!%5Cn%5Cn%3C%3C%2F33%27%5Ba%252%3A%3A2%5D%2C%27...%27%29%5Ba-i%3E1%5D)

Comment: `['...','!','.'][(i==a-1)*(1+i%2)]` and `' not'*(i%2)`.

Comment: Thanks FryAmTheEggman and orlp. I added parts of what you two suggested but would feel guilty taking all of FryAmTheEggman's comment.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 98 bytes

```julia
r=rand(3:20)
for i=1:r println("Loves me"*(i%2>0?" not":"")*(i<r?"...":i%2>0?".\n</3":"!\n<3"))end
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
# Define a random number 3 ≤ r ≤ 20
r = rand(3:20)

for i = 1:r
    # The loveless lines occur when i is even
    println("Loves me" *
            (i % 2 > 0 ? " not" : "") *
            (i < r ? "..." : i % 2 > 0 ? ".\n</3" : "!\n<3"))
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## UNIX shell, 193 bytes

```
t=$(seq 2 19|shuf|head -1)
l=t
p=...
while [ $t -ge 0 ];do
case $l:$t in t:0)p=!;h=\<3;;f:0)p=.;h=\</3;;esac
case $l in t)l=f;n=;; f)l=t;n=\ not;;esac
t=$((t-1))
echo Loves me$n$p
done
echo $h
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>210</s> <s>209</s> <s>203</s> <s>200</s> 177 bytes

- <s>flipped `i%2==0` to `i%2<1`</s>
- trimmed `{ ... }` braces for `for`-loop, moved `e` declaration to loop
- re-ordered conditionals
- removed modifiers and unnecessary parentheses, reworked [`Random` usage](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26026/21697) and increment for `i`

Note: newline is added below for formatting on this site, the count above is for a *single* line.

```
class F{public static void main(String[]a){for(int e=3+(int)(Math.random()*18),i=0;++i<=e;)
System.out.println("Loves me"+(i%2>0?i<e?"...":"!\n<3":" not."+(i<e?"..":"\n</3")));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class F {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        for (int e = 3 + (int) (Math.random() * 18), i = 0; ++i <= e; )
            System.out.println("Loves me" + (i % 2 > 0 ? i < e ? "..." : "!\n<3"
                    : " not." + (i < e ? ".." : "\n</3")));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save 13 bytes by removing public.

Comment: @Luminous I'll still need to keep the one for `main()` though...

Comment: @TimmyD I second that.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <strike>123, 121, 109</strike> 106 characters (108 bytes)

(with a little ♥♥♥cheating♥♥♥)

```
O;main(o){for(o=time(O)%18+3;o-O++;printf("Loves me%s%s\n",O&1?"":" not",o-O?"...":O%2?"!\n♥":".\n</3"));}
```

There's also a [broken heart](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%92%94) Unicode point at 1f494, but I had difficulties finding a font which implements it.

Comment: [This](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#O%3Bmain%28o%29%7Bfor%28o%3Dtime%28O%3D0%29%2518%2B3%3Bo-O%2B%2B%3Bprintf%28%22Loves%20me%25s%25s%5Cn%22%2CO%261%3F%22%22%3A%22%20not%22%2Co-O%3F%22...%22%3AO%252%3F%22!%22%3A%22.%22%29%29%3Bputs%28O%261%3F%22%3C%2F3%22%3A%22%E2%99%A5%22%29%3B%7D) shows 120 characters and 122 bytes...

Comment: I don't think you need `O=0`, because `C` auto-initialize ints to `0`?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Good find! In a previous version I had O in `main(o,O)` where it had to be initialized.

Comment: Nice, I like it! I didn't think of using `time` as a random number... Clever!

Comment: @MatthewRock If you think about it, all the other program using `srand(time(0))` will change their answer with the same frequency. The srand is completely useless :-)

Comment: @TimmyD I believe it's the way the unicode character is counted. In vim, it was 123 bytes including the final newline.

Comment: Even though you "need"  a trailing newline according to C documentation, most compilers actually don't care, and as long as [one referenceable implementation](https://ideone.com/qrnx0D) works that way all the time, it's valid here :P

Comment: Why don't you change ♥♥♥ for `<3`? It's  actually 1 byte less. Plus, your answer - as for now - doesn't meet the requirements.

Comment: @MatthewRock Guess I'm a bit anarchic and like to break^Wcreatively twist the rules. If the winner is the shortest program, C has no chance anyway, with CJam around.

Comment: @Jens Creatively twisting the rules is for [tag:popularity-contest]s, which this is *not* :P

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, <s>121</s> <s>119</s> 111 Bytes

```
$i=2..19|Random;1..$i|%{"Loves me$(if(!($_%2)){" not"})..."};"Loves me$(if(!($i%2)){"!`n<"}else{" not.`n</"})3"
```

<sub>Edit--actually shorter to explicitly include `"Loves me"` rather than declaring `$l`</sub>

<sub>Edit2--forgot that I can golf `for()` loops by pipelining...durr...</sub>

Not too shabby. Uses inline code execution blocks `$(...)` to dynamically adjust the printed string as we're `for()`-looping. Note that because this uses an implicit `Get-` in front of `Random` to save a couple bytes, this may operate extremely slowly on certain PowerShell versions. [Reference](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/778/42963)

Expanded below for clarification:

```
# Create a collection of (2,3,4,...18,19) and pipe it as input to Get-Random
$i = 2..19 | Get-Random

# Create a collection of (1,2,...$i-1,$i) and pipe it to seed a ForEach-Object loop
1..$i | ForEach-Object {
  if(!($_%2)) {
    # If the input number is even, we're on an even line
    Write-Output "Loves me not..."
  }
  Else {
    # The input number is odd
    Write-Output "Loves me..."
  }
}
If(!($i%2)) {
  # Our random number is odd
  Write-Output "Loves me!"
  Write-Output "<3"
}
Else {
  # Our random number is even
  Write-Output "Loves me not."
  Write-Output "</3"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## C++, <del>210</del> <del>193</del> <del>184</del> 168 bytes

In C++.. because.. Why not?
:)

```
#include <iostream>
main(){auto&c=std::cout;srand(time(0));int i,j=3+rand()%18;while(i++<j)c<<"Loves me"<<(i%2?"":" not")<<(i==j?"":"...\n");c<<(j%2?"!\n<3":".\n</3");}
```

Live: 
<del>[210](https://ideone.com/5n5sbi)</del>
<del>[193](https://ideone.com/5XwIuN)</del>
<del>[184](https://ideone.com/p8gZdN)</del>
[168](https://ideone.com/WjnH0j)

Just hope that any of my changes are not platform dependent.

Thanks to [Ben Voigt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/11335/ben-voigt) for the help. Also, thanks to all the comments, they were very helpful.

Comment: Humn.. just realize its 3 to 20. I will fix that later. Probably will add 2 more bytes... `j=3+(int)(rand()*17.0/RAND_MAX)`

Comment: You can save a lot by replacing `#define c cout` and `using namespace std;` by `auto&c=std::cout;`

Comment: Also save some with `int i=0,j=rand()*20.0/RAND_MAX;while(i<j)`

Comment: Hello, found a bug: Last line should be "Loves me!", not "Loves me."

Comment: `20.0` could be shortened to `20.` or `20f`.

Comment: Do you really need () around rand?

Comment: You are correct. We dont need the ().. neither the {} in the while if we change the `;c<<` to `<<`. I just found [this](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx) nice article about random. To be [3,20] inclusive, I have to change to 18.f. Just found out that I could have used `%` instead of `RAND_MAX`... but if I change it now will look similar to tonysdg answer. Trying to see where else it can be optimized.

Comment: I'd say it's okay - C and C++ are similar. And right now this code is longer than Java...

Comment: And [actually you can just use time instead of srand and rand ;)](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58098/15174)

Comment: You can remove the space in `#include <iostream>`. @MatthewRock Longer than Java. wat. It's actually 9 bytes shorter... I knew it was impossible!

Comment: @RK. At the time of writing my comment, the code was longer than Java's.

Comment: I do not understand how it can work without #include <time.h>...

Comment: @GuillaumeLethuillier thats a good question. I didnt know for sure myself.. I had the idea it was included somewhere on `ostream`. Just google'd and looks like it's something like that, `ctime` is used for [locale support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016646/why-does-iostream-include-time-h)

Answer (score 3):

## Groovy, 110 bytes

A groovy kind of love:

```
int r=Math.random()*18;print((0..r+2).collect{"Loves me"+" not"*(it%2)}.join('...\n')+['!\n<3','.\n</3'][r%2])
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 117 bytes

```
from random import*
n=randint(3,20)
print"...\n".join("Loves me"+i%2*" not"for i in range(n))+[".\n</3","!\n<3"][n%2]
```

Observe that every `Loves me( not)?` is followed by `...` and a newline, except for the last one. So this looks like a job for `join`.

Comment: A bit late but `".!\n\n<</33"[n%2::2]` is 2 bytes shorter.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yeah, I did see that but decided not to steal it from Loovjo. In the meantime, someone else has posted exactly that solution. [shrug]

Comment: I hadn't noticed someone else posting it, but I am pretty sure [my comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57984/loves-me-loves-me-not/58024?noredirect=1#comment139524_57994) was the first that had it in it, so you can use it if you want :P

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>141</s> <s>132</s> <s>128</s> <s>114</s> <s>111</s> 109 bytes

#### Code

```r
k=sample(3:23,1);for(i in 1:k)cat("Loves",c("me not...\n","me...\n","me not.\n</3","me!\n<3")[1+i%%2+2*!i<k])
```

#### Ungolfed

```r
k <- sample(3:23, 1)        # Generates random "k" number from 3 to 23
for(i in 1:k) {             # Loop this block increasing i from 1 until k by 1
  cat                       # Concatenate and paste everything inside this block
  ("Loves",                 # Push "Loves" on every iterations of the loop
      c(                    # Create a vector of strings
        "me not...\n",      # Push string to the index "1" of vector
        "me...\n",          #   to the index "2"
        "me not.\n</3",     #   to the index "3"
        "me!\n<3"           #   to the index "4"
        )[1+i%%2            # Subset the vector by the index (1 or 2)
          +2*!i<k])}        #   if final iteration of loop then index += 2 (3 or 4)
```

I've took some inspiration from [Eric Brooks](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42322/eric-brooks) code.

Edit 1: Now the code correctly outputs the last punctuation as pointed
   out by [Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478)
Edit 2: Changed the for loop to a sapply and included the hearts
   inside the last line string.
Edit 3: Removed the `{}` and changed `+(x==k)*2` to `+2*!x<k`
Edit 4: Back to for loop and removed the `()` from `(i%%2)+1`
Edit 5: Wrote `me` 4 times and removed the `sep=""`

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>119</s> <s>111</s> 105 bytes

```r
x<-sample(3:20,1);cat(rep(c("Loves me...\n","Loves me not...\n"),x)[1:x]);cat(ifelse(x%%2==1,"<3","</3"))
```

Edits 1,2: Coding the two options explicitly is saving space.

Comment: You can save a byte by using `=` for assignment rather than `<-` and another by doing `x%%2>0` in place of `x%%2==1`. Also note that this doesn't handle the last line correctly; there should be a `.` or `!` rather than `...`. (See example output in the question.)

Comment: @Alex A. You don't need `x%%2>0` either; just `x%%2`

Comment: Good points, thanks. I need to go back and fix the ending

Answer (score 1):

## C 226 bytes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
void main(){srand(time(NULL));int i=rand()%18+3;int j;for(j=0;j<i;j++)printf("Loves me%s%s\n",(j%2)?" not":"",(j==i-1)?(j%2)?".":"!":"...");printf("<%s3\n",(j%2)?"":"/");}
```

(With formatting)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i = rand()%18 + 3;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("Loves me%s%s\n", (j % 2) ? " not" : "", (j==i-1) ? (j % 2) ? "." : "!" : "...");
    printf("<%s3\n", (j%2) ? "" : "/");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove return type from main (-5 bytes), make i and j global with default type (-8 bytes, -3 more because of default 0 in j), use 0 instead of NULL (-3). Other things - use only one variable and make the loop counting down maybe. Import stdio is not usually needed when golfing.

Answer (score 1):

## mSL, <strike>178</strike> <strike>176</strike> <strike>156</strike> 154 bytes

Edit 1: Changed `== 0` to `< 1`
Edit 2: Removed unnecessary whitespace, thanks AlexA!
Edit 3: Removed parentheses

```
alias l {
var %n 1
while %n <= $rand(3,20) {
var %m $+(Love me,$iif($calc(%n % 2) < 1,$chr(32) $+ not),...)
echo %m
inc %n
}
echo $iif(n isin %m,</3,<3)
}
```

Comment: Your solution is currently [176](https://goo.gl/KkOwxA) bytes, not 177. Is all of the whitespace necessary? If not, you could shorten your code by a significant amount simply by removing unneeded whitespace.

Comment: @AlexA. Oh don't know why I wrote 177, and thanks for pointing out the necessity of whitespace, it is indeed not needed!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 115 bytes

```
from random import*
n=randint(2,20)
print'...\n'.join('Loves me'+i%2*' not'for i in range(n))+'.!\n\n<</33'[n%2::2]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium), 265 Bytes

```
func main(){rnd=new Random();times=rnd.next(3,21);println("Loves me...");for(x=0;x<times-1;x++){if(x%2==0)println("Loves me not...");else println("Loves me...");}if((times-1)%2==0){println("Loves me not.");println("</3");}else{println("Loves me!");println("<3");}}
```

The answer has been golfed.

Comment: Your solution is currently [458 bytes](https://goo.gl/mzOwxV), not 523. You can better your score by removing unnecessary whitespace and shortening variable names. See [the other Hassium solution](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58090/20469) for examples.

Comment: As I noted on the other Hassium answer, the random number generator seems to be extremely biased. I ran this 500 times with the latest version and only got two `</3`.

Comment: +Dennis The Random generator is built directly on top of the C# Random number generator. See: https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium/blob/master/src/Hassium/HassiumObjects/Random/HassiumRandom.cs

Comment: It doesn't seem to get seeded correctly. If I execute `rnd = new Random();rnd.next(0,2);` 1000 times, the distribution is OK. However, if I execute `rnd = new Random();` once and `rnd.next(0,2);` 1000 times, I always get exactly 533 `0`s and 467 `1`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium), <s>161</s> 165 bytes

I golfed [Reagan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58083/25314).

```
func main()println(range(-1,t=new Random().next(3,21)).select(x=>"Loves me"+(x%2==0?" not":"")+(x==t-2?(x%2==0?".":"!"):"...")).join("\n"),"\n",t%2==0?"</3":"<3");
```

Unleashing the power of Hassium.

#### Ungolfed version

```
func main()
{
    t = new Random().next(3,21); # initialize the love number
    loveNumber = range(-1, t); # creates an array like this Array { -1 0 1 2 ... ... up to n } where n is a random number between 3 and 21 }
    loves = loveNumber.select(x => # iterates through the array
                                {
                                    ret = "Loves me";
                                    if (x % 2 == 0) # check if x is even
                                    {
                                        ret += " not"; # add ' not' to the result
                                    }
                                    ret += (x == t ? (x % 2 == 0 ? "." : "!") : "...");
                                    return ret;
                                }).join("\n"); # join the result with Unix newlines (\n)
    println(loves); # print it
    println(t%2==0?"</3":"<3");
}
```

Comment: The random number generator seems to be extremely biased. I ran this 500 times and only got two `</3`.

Comment: @Dennis however, if you got various lengths, I would say it's fine - I specified that any distribution is allowed - so although 2 in 500 isn't much, it's still acceptable, by the rules.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>191</strike> <strike>187</strike> <strike>146</strike> 165 Bytes

```
$x=rand(5,22);for($i=2;++$i<=$x;){echo"\nLoves me";if($i%2<1)echo" not";if($i<$x)echo"...";if($i==$x&&$i%2<1){echo".\n</3\n";}elseif($i==$x&&$i%2>0){echo"!\n<3\n";}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
$x=rand(5,22);
for($i=2;++$i<=$x;){
    echo "\nLoves me";
    if($i%2<1) echo " not";
    if($i<$x) echo "...";
    if($i==$x && $i%2<1){
        echo ".\n</3\n";
    }
    elseif($i==$x && $i%2>0){
        echo "!\n<3\n";
    }
}
```

48,49 bytes for pyth and cjam ... wow :)

Comment: Changed $i%2==0 to $i%2<1 (x2) and $i%2!=0 to $i%2>0 (x2)

Comment: turns out ternary operators are not the best answer at all times :)

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 97 bytes

```
$_='She loves me...
'x(3+rand 18);s/(me.*?)me/$1me not/gs;s/e...
$/e!
<3/;s/t...
$/t.
<\/3/;print
```

Readable version:

```
$_="She loves me...\n"x(3+rand 18);
s/(me.*?)me/$1me not/gs;
s/e...$/e!\n<3/;
s/t...$/t.\n<\/3/;
print
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# (160)

The code is inspired by [**the answer**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58062/15235) from [**h.j.k.**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21697/h-j-k), credit goes to him.

```
class P{static void Main(){for(int e=3+new Random().Next(0,18),i=0;++i<=e;)Console.WriteLine("Loves me"+(i%2>0?i<e?"...":"!\n<3":" not."+(i<e?"..":"\n</3")));}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
class P
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        for (int e = 3 + new Random().Next(0, 18), i = 0; ++i <= e;)
            Console.WriteLine("Loves me" + (i % 2 > 0 ? i < e ? "..." : "!\n<3" : " not." + (i < e ? ".." : "\n</3")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, <s>137</s> 132 bytes

Probably can be golfed a lot more, but here it is for now:

```
t=math.random(3,20)for i=1,t do io.write(i%2==0 and"Loves me"or"Loves me not")print(i==t and(i%2==0 and"!\n<3"or".\n</3")or"...")end
```

Code explanation and ungolfed:

```
t=math.random(3,20) --Generates a random number between 1 and 30. We need to assign it to a variable to check if the loop is over later.
for i=1,t do
  io.write(i%2==0 and"Loves me"or"Loves me not") --If i%2 is 0 write without a newline Loves me, if not print Loves me not.
  print(i==t and (i%2==0 and"!\n<3" or ".\n</3") or "...") --If it is not the end of the loop, put ..., else if we ended on an even print ! a newline, and then a heart, but if we ended on an odd put ., a newline and a broken heart :(
end
```

Edit: Chopped off some whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 55 bytes

```
“¢zḞzƘFq»,;¥“ not”ṁ18X+2¤j“...¶”µċ⁷Ḃ©”/ẋ;3⁾¶<;®ị⁾.!¤;⁸;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5xDi6oe7phXdWyGW@Gh3TrWh5YCxRTy8kseNcx9uLPR0CJC2@jQkiygoJ6e3qFtQNFDW490P2rc/nBH06GVQK7@w13d1saPGvcd2mZjfWjdw91AyX16ioeWWD9q3GH9/z8A)

As usual Jelly sucks with strings.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>85</s> 88 bytes

*+3 bytes thanks Veskah: That's a good point.*

```powershell
0..(1..19|Random)|%{($l='Loves me')+' not'*($n=$_%2)+'...'}
$l+('!
<3',' not.
</3')[!$n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30BPT8NQT8/QsiYoMS8lP1ezRrVaQyXHVt0nvyy1WCE3VV1TW10hL79EXUtDJc9WJV7VCCigp6enXsulkqOtoa7IZWOsrgNWosdlo2@srhmtqJIX@/8/AA)

Comment: This can generate "Loves me, Loves me not </3", which, based on how I read the specs, is below the minimum number of lines.

Comment: Indeed `of *3* to 20 lines inclusive`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [ß](https://github.com/minxomat/-S-), 138 bytes

Works (with valid output). More *a* solution than *the* solution, could be golfed further:

```
R=ß!G3,20,1)µL='Loves me'µD='...@LF@'µ€L&D)°/X=0°(R-1µ€L)°\mod(X,2)=0°{€' not')µ€D)°)€L)°\mod(R,2)°{µ€'!'&@LF&'<3')°]€' not.'&@LF&'</3')°}
```

Sample:

```
$ sharps "R=ß!G3,20,1)µL='Loves me'µD='...@LF@'µ€L&D)°/X=0°(R-1µ€L)°\mod(X,2)=0°{€' not')µ€D)°)€L)°\mod(R,2)°{µ€'!'&@LF&'<3')°]€' not.'&@LF&'</3')°}"
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me...
Loves me not...
Loves me!
<3
```

Answer (score 0):

## Japt, <s>77</s> 76 bytes

```
Mq17 +3 o £`Lov ´{Y%2?" not":""}...`Ã
U· +`
Lov ´`+(UÊ%2?" not.
</3":"!
<3
```

Probably can be golfed a lot further.

[Try it Online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a1&code=TXExNyArMyBvIKNgTG92gyC0e1klMj8iIG5vdCI6IiJ9Li4uYMMKVbcgK2AKTG92gyC0YCsoVcolMj8iIG5vdC4KPC8zIjoiIQo8Mw==&input=)

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Python 3, <strike>179</strike> <strike>171</strike> 167 bytes

```
from random import*;n=randint(3,20);s=""
for i in range(n):
    b=i%2==0;s+="Loves me"+(""if b else" not")
    if i<n-1:s+="...\n"
s+="!\n<3"if b else".\n</3";print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 78 bytes

```
-(l)Loves me{&| not}{
-l<3||l>20||RANDOM(0,1):<>...
->l
}{l%2:!|.}
<{1-l%2:/}3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNH0ye/LLVYITe1Wq1GIS@/pLaaSzfHxrimJsfOyKCmJsjRz8XfV8NAx1DTysZOT0@PS9cuh6u2OkfVyEqxRq@Wy6baUBfE0a81/u/i6hTqbqUQlJinUJ1Tq5BZklqUWJKZn1f8HwA)

\$p(n) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^{n-3}}& \text{if }3 \le n \le 19\\
\frac{1}{2^{16}}& \text{if }n=20\\
0& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\$

This is probably my least favourite of the three approaches I tried. But the others clocked in at [79](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v9fVyNH0ye/LLVYITe1Wq1GIS@/pLa6pqa6rgYd6Nql1tbq6elx6drlcNmmclXnqBpZKdbo1XLZVBvqgjj6tcb/XVydQt2tFIIS8xSqc2oVMktSixJLMvPziv8DAA) and [80](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v@/riQ1t0Ch2DbI0c/F31fDWMfIQJNLVyNH0ye/LLVYITe1Wq1GIS@/pLaaSzdHt9jKxk5PT49L1y6Hq7Y6R9XISrFGr5bLptpQF8TRrzX@7@LqFOpupRCUmKdQnVOrkFmSWpRYkpmfV/wfAA) bytes.