# #Hashtag_or_not

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

In this code golf challenge, you will verify hashtags!

## #What_your_code_should_do

Input is a string. Output a truthy value if it is a valid hashtag, and a falsy value otherwise.

We define a string as a valid Hashtag if ...

- It starts with a hash (`#`).
- It doesn't have a number right after the hashtag (e.g. `#2016USElection` isn't a  valid hashtag).
- It doesn't have any "special characters" (i.e. any character that isn't an alphabet, underscore (`_`) or a number).

You can assume that the input only contains ASCII characters. (It would be unfair if we did Unicode too.)

## #Rules

Basic [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

## #Examples

Truthy:

```
#
#e
#_ABC 
#thisisanunexpectedlylongstringxoxoxoxo
#USElection2016
```

Falsy:

```
Hello, World!
#12thBday
#not-valid
#alsoNotValid!
#!not_a_hash
```

Comment: Is `#` really a valid hashtag?

Comment: @Adám Why not??

Comment: Is `#öäü` valid?

Comment: Should the empty string return falsy? Or are we allowed to require at least one character?

Comment: `#` is not a valid hashtag by any system, Facebook or Twitter it also breaks the rules set also im not sure #_ABC is valid again on them but im not certain of that.

Comment: I assume `an alphabet` means ascii uppercase or lowercase letter? i.e. `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`?

Comment: A # is not a hashtag. It's a hash. It, followed by a string is what social media networks refer to as a hashtag. It's a tag, which starts with a hash.

Comment: Will we receive empty string as an input?

Comment: Is printing nothing equals to False?

Comment: @LeakyNun No, You won't.

Comment: This is similar to the definition of a valid identifier in many languages. Not sure if abusing `eval` would be possible though.

Comment: You should either allow `-` or disallow both `-` and `_`, in my opinion.

Comment: @Peanut Why? The challenge works perfectly well as is, and `_` is treated as a word character in a *lot* of contexts while `-` almost never is.

Answer (score 19):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 12 bytes

```
^#(?!\d)\w*$
```

Prints `1` for hashtags and `0` otherwise.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApeIyg_IVxkKVx3KiQ&input=I1VTRWxlY3Rpb24yMDE2CiMKI3RoaXNpc2FudW5leHBlY3RlZGx5bG9uZ3N0cmluZ3hveG94b3hvCiNIYXNodGFnX29yX25vdAojX2hhc2gKIzEydGhCZGF5CkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEKIzIwMTZVU0VsZWN0aW9uCiMj) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

Not much to explain here, this is quite a literal implementation of the definition: `^` and `$` are just anchors ensuring that the match covers the entire string, `#` checks that the string starts with a `#`, `(?!\d)` ensures that the next character *isn't* a digit (without advancing the regex engine's position), `\w*` checks that we can reach the end of the string with zero or more letters, digits or underscores.

By default, Retina counts the number of matches of the given regex, which is why this gives `1` for valid hash tags and `0` otherwise.

Comment: In Perl, `(?!\d)` is `(?=\D)`... but I don't know how you've written Retina. Is it possible you could use `(?\D)` without the `=` and save a byte? (If not, is it worth editing the language so that's doable?)

Comment: @msh210 `(?!\d)` is different from `(?=\D)` in that the latter requires *some* character after the current position while the former is satisfied with the end of the string. Regardless of that, adjusting the regex flavour is currently not possible (since I'm just handing the regex to .NET's regex engine), but making such changes is on the roadmap somewhere (very far) down the line.

Comment: That said, I don't think I'll make the `=` optional. The entire `(?...)` syntax was chosen for extensibility, in that the character after the `?` is never optional and determines which kind of group this is, and I don't think I want to give up that extensibility.

Comment: (re your first comment) Duh, of course, I shoulda noted that. But it's irrelevant to this answer. (re your second) Yeah, makes sense. There is after all also `(?{` and `(??` and `(?<` (both for capturing groups and for lookbehind) and `(?-` and `(?1` and of course the basic `(?:`. And maybe some I;ve missed.

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 22 bytes

**21 bytes code +1 for `-p`**

```pl
$_=/^#([a-z_]\w*)?$/i
```

Prints 1 if it's a valid hashtag, empty string otherwise.

#### Usage

```sh
perl -pe '$_=/^#([a-z_]\w*)?$/i' <<< '#'
1
perl -pe '$_=/^#([a-z_]\w*)?$/i' <<< '#_test'
1
perl -pe '$_=/^#([a-z_]\w*)?$/i' <<< '#1test'
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks for [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender) (and another 4 using his [lookaround method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/85621))

---

### Perl, 18 bytes

**17 bytes code +1 for `-p`**

Using Martin's lookaround this can be much shorter!

```pl
$_=/^#(?!\d)\w*$/
```

Comment: You copied Martin's one and edited it, right?

Comment: @MatthewRoh The second answer uses Martin's mechanism yes. He did say I could use it, but I didn't want it to be my main answer as I didn't come up with it myself! I've added it for comparison. Retina still beats Perl easily in this type of challenge!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 25 bytes

```js
s=>/^#(?!\d)\w*$/.test(s)
```

```js
F = s => /^#(?!\d)\w*$/.test(s)
input.oninput = () => result.innerHTML = input.value ? F(input.value) ? '\ud83d\udc8e' : '\ud83d\udca9' : '\ud83d\udcad';
```

```css
#input, #result {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
#input {
  line-height: 2em;
}
#result {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text"/> <span id="result">&#x1f4ad</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

## C, 80 bytes

Function `f()` takes the string as an argument and modifies `int *b` to either 1 or 0 to indicate truthy/falsy.

```
f(char*p,int*b){for(*b=(*p==35)&&!isdigit(p[1]);*p;++p)*b&=isalnum(*p)||*p==95;}
```

If the string always has at least one character (i.e. never an empty string), a byte can be shaved off for 79 bytes:

```
f(char*p,int*b){for(*b=(*p==35)&&!isdigit(p[1]);*++p;)*b&=isalnum(*p)||*p==95;}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 41 bytes

```
import re
re.compile('#(?!\d)\w*$').match
```

Comment: This should be absolutely fine. Since match objects are truthy and `None` is falsey, I think dropping the `bool()` is okay.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, thanks for clarifying it!

Comment: This generates truthy value for “#fix me Gábor” too. BTW, I see the rules are getting ignored by others too, but this we used to consider a snippet, which usually is not accepted as answer unless the question explicitly allows them.

Comment: Thanks, I rewrote it to handle the case you wrote and made it a lambda function.

Comment: How about `re.compile('#(?!\d)\w*$').match`? It’s acceptable to drop the `f=`, BTW.

Comment: Oh, nice idea, it will be then a function too!

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 55 bytes

```
"#"|h"#",?b@lL'(eE,@A:"1234567890":"_"c'eE),@A:"_"ce~hL
```

This uses no regex.

#### Explanation

```
Main predicate, Input (?) is a string

  "#"                           ? = "#"
|                             Or
  h"#",                         First character of ? is "#"
  ?b@lL                         L is the rest of the chars of ? lowercased
  '(                            It is not possible for any char of L that...
    eE,                           Call this char E
    @A:"1234567890":"_"c          Concatenate the lowercase alphabet with the digits and "_"
    'eE                           E is not a member of that concatenated string
   ),                           
   @A:"_"c                      Concatenate the lowercase alphabet with "_"
   e~hL                         One char of that concatenated string is the first char of L
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, <s>103</s> 93 bytes

```
all((c=='_'or c.isalpha()*i>0)^(i<1and'#'==c)^(c.isdigit()*i>1)for i,c in enumerate(input()))
```

The `#` being `True` killed me here, I had to enumerate the string to avoid an index error on the single character input.

Comment: +1. Nice! I completely forgot the `isalpha()` method on my py3 answer :D "#" being true, also destroyed me.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell v2+, 25 bytes

```
$args-match'^#(?!\d)\w*$'
```

Using [Martin's regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85621/42963), just wrapped up in PowerShell's `-match` operator coupled with the input `$args`. For truthy/falsey values, this will return the string itself on a match (a truthy value) or nothing on a non-match (a falsey value). This is because when a comparison operator is applied against an array, it [returns anything](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/745/42963) that satisfies that operator.

A couple examples (wrapped in a `[bool]` cast to make the output more clear):

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> [bool](.\hashtag-or-not.ps1 '#2016Election')
False

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> [bool](.\hashtag-or-not.ps1 'Hello, World!')
False

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> [bool](.\hashtag-or-not.ps1 '#')
True

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> [bool](.\hashtag-or-not.ps1 '')
False

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> [bool](.\hashtag-or-not.ps1 '#USElection2016')
True
```

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>52</s> <s>46</s> 43 bytes

<sup>Saved <s>6</s> 9 bytes due to [@MartinEnder](http://ppcg.lol/users/8478).</sup>

```
StringMatchQ@RegularExpression@"#(?!\d)\w*"
```

Function. Takes a string as input, and returns `True` or `False` as output. Pretty simple, just matches against the regex `/#(?!\d)\w*/`.

Comment: I have reason to believe that this won't work for inputs like `hello#world` since you don't have the beginning and end string anchors. I don't know Mathematica though so I'm not sure.

Comment: All righty, I can live with that. Have your +1

Answer (score 3):

### Python3 - <strike>156</strike> 128 bytes

```
lambda n:n=="#"or(n[0]=="#")*all(any([47<ord(c)<58,64<ord(c)<91,ord(c)==95,96<ord(c)<123])for c in n[1:]+"0")*~(47<ord(n[1])<58)
```

A solution that doesn't use regex. 0 is falsey and every other value is truthy.

Thanks to @LeakyNun for saving bytes!

Comment: @LeakyNun I had to remove the `+0` after `n[1:]`, but sadly, still didn't work :/ Gave false to "#d".

Comment: @LeakyNun still doesn't work :( Again, had to remove `+0` but fails on "#d". I tested it on Python3 though. Not sure if it will work on Python2

Comment: @LeakyNun Just plain false.

Comment: @LeakyNun Throws `IndexOutOfRange` for "#" and `False` for "#d".

Comment: `lambda n:n=="#"or(n[0]=="#")*all(any([47<ord(c)<58,64<ord(c)<91,ord(c)==95,96<ord(c)<123])for c in n[1:]+"0")*~(47<ord(n[1])<58)` for 128 bytes. [Proof that it works](http://ideone.com/70mKow)

Comment: @LeakyNun Now that works. The return values are pretty odd: "12" --> 0, "#" --> true, "#ab" --> -1, "#1b" --> -2. Can I just treat every output other output than "True" as falsey?

Comment: [Here is the meta post for reference](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2194/48934).

Comment: @LeakyNun Thanks! I managed to golf my solution down to 131 bytes, but yours is currently better, so I'll take it.

Comment: No, Falsey is 0, every other value will be truthy, in this case.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oops, I'll fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>22</s> 20 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Without RegEx:

```
{0≤⎕NC 1↓⍵,⎕A}∧'#'=⊃
```

-2 thanks to ngn

Comment: Oh, wow. There are still people who know APL. It's 37 years since I used it!

Comment: @Auspex APL is well and alive, but quite few features have been added in those years.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>37</s> <s>56</s> <s>54</s> 43 bytes

Thanks to @LuisMendo for removing 8 bytes!

```
@(s)s(1)==35&(isvarname(s(2:end))|nnz(s)<2)
```

Not very golfy, but very built-inny.
Edit: The original code accepted strings with no leading '#'. I guess I should have stuck with regex.

Test suite on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ihx7a5).

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 79 bytes

```
lambda x:x=='#'or(1>x[1].isdigit())&x[1:].replace('_','').isalnum()&('#'==x[0])
```

First golfing attempt. Ungolfed version:

```
def f(x):
    if x == '#':
        return True
    else:
        return x[0]=='#' and x[1:].replace('_','').isalnum() and not x[1].isdigit()
```

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <s>59</s> <s>55</s> 54 bytes

### Code

```
s=arg[1]print(load(s:sub(2).."=0")and s:sub(1,1)=="#")
```

### How it works:

1. Check if the rest of the characters can be a valud Lua identifier (identifiers in Lua follow the same rules as hashtags.)
2. Check if the first character is a `#`.

Takes input from the command line. Prints `true` if the string is a valid hashtag, otherwise, it prints `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 30 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input from the cell `A1` checks it against the RE2 expression and outputs the result to the calling cell.

```
=RegexMatch(A1,"^#([a-z_]\w*)?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

Code:

```
¬'#Qs¦A«¬d_sDžjKQP
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqwnI1FzwqZBwqvCrGRfc0TFvmpLUVA&input=I1Byb2dyYW1taW5nX1B1enpsZXNfYW5kX0NvZGVfR29sZg).

Answer (score 1):

## [Standard ML](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>121</s> <s>118</s> 107 bytes

```ml
(fn#"#"::a=>(fn x::r=>x> #"@"andalso List.all(fn#"_"=>1=1|c=>Char.isAlphaNum c)a|e=>1=1)a|e=>1=0)o explode;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLasMwEDzXX6EolxiSEOfQg41M41DooeQS2h76MIutxoK11lhKcSD/7kpWCkVI2h3NaKQxLa5atKTHcfGt53zO0xRE7mo2pGkv8iFnc/7AQdeAhtizMnYNiBO55CJPRHKtRL5voF8rs8OugcO5ZVUMVzmd/hWbmJgcOqRaZuMPILPSWCZYCx1bdL3SlhHzvkbk5ot/aB47oCDCtaWjdYST65WNs8ir3VS1k79Hd@7RS7/KsJW7Yh8q2yijDOizdsaysrLGC5I@mem2gcII3JfjIzqKIr3dJPf8M7go/d/nSSLSkr1Rj/UsyJKtbYoaLqHTZFeTILQ@sQPZV4/c@DNHKaFswDTeY8pgUmRRyMB//IbfzLPxFw)
Functional solution without using regex. Declares an anonymous function which is bond to the implicit result identifier `it`.

```ml
> val it = fn : string -> bool    
- it "#valid_hash";
> val it = true : bool
```

Comment: `isAlphaNum$orelse` that's rather threatening...

Comment: @cat this might be the sole positive thing one can say about such verbose boolean operators as `orelse` and `andalso`.

Comment: It's like, `AlphaNum`, **`orelse`**!! (`orelse what?`)

Comment: One might consider the `o explode` at the end to be quite threatening too ...

Comment: **`orelse explode`** D:

Comment: SML seems quite scary, I don't think I could handle that all day :c

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 19 bytes

```
\#.^It,!It\_D-PRkq|
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%5C%23.%5EIt%2C%21It%5C_D-PRkq%7C&input=%23)

Quick fix for tonight

Comment: @kenorb rebooted it, ping me if any more issues

Comment: `#123` returns still nothing, shouldn't return 0?

Comment: Nothing is a boolean false

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 97 Bytes <strike>70 Bytes 56 Bytes</strike>

```
lambda x:s=x[2:];b=x[1];all(x!="#",[x[0]=="#",any[b.isalpha(),"_"in b],any[s.isalnum(),"_"in s]])
```

(Code changed) <strike>Human readable</strike>

```
x=input()
if x[0]=="#" and x[1].isalpha() and str(x)[2:].isalnum():
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site! Functions are also allowed, so you could shorten this quite a bit with `lambda x:all(True==[x[0]=="#",x[1].isalpha(),x[2:].isalpha()])`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: I hate to be the bringer of bad news, but doesn't this [fail for '#'](https://ideone.com/ySpvCc), which the OP says is truthy? Won't it also fail if the hashtag contains any underscores, which are false under `isalpha`?

Comment: @TheBikingViking sorry, I will try to fix this now

Comment: It might be worth marking your answer as non-competing until it is fixed, to prevent any downvoting.

Comment: @TheBikingViking Is it okay now?

Comment: Try running it past all the test cases, and see if it returns the correct output.

Comment: @TheBikingViking That's not what non-competing means. Non-competing is not an excuse for an invalid submission. The correct procedure is to delete the answer, fix it, then undelete it.

Comment: @Mego Ah, okay, Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

## GNU grep, 15 + 2 = 17 bytes

```sh
grep -Ei '^#([a-z_]\w*)?$'
```

#### Test:

```sh
$ echo '#
#e
#_ABC
#thisisanunexpectedlylongstringxoxoxoxo
#USElection2016
Hello, World!
#12thBday
#not-valid
#alsoNotValid!' | grep -Ei '^#([a-z_][a-z0-9_]*)?$'
```

Output:

```
#
#e
#_ABC
#thisisanunexpectedlylongstringxoxoxoxo
#USElection2016
```

Answer (score 1):

## Sed 19 + 2 = 21 bytes

```
/^#([a-z_]\w*)?$/Ip
```

This filters out all non-hashtags and outputs valid hashtags.

Run as `sed -rn "/^#$|^#[a-z]\w*$/Ip"`. Quit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (send EOF).

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 16 + <s>3</s> 1 (`n` flag) = <s>19</s> 17 bytes

Uses `0` as truthy and `nil` as falsy.

```
p~/^#(?!\d)\w*$/
```

Run it as `ruby -ne 'p~/^#(?!\d)\w*$/'`. Thanks to @manatwork for fixing the bash error when running the program.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and always enclose code in single quotes. Otherwise the shell will attempt (or even worse, successfully perform) all kind of expansions. (Regarding the current issue with `!`, see [Event Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) in man bash.)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 54 bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]`, checks if the value of the cell matches the `Like` pattern, and outputs as `Boolean` to the VBE immediate window

```vb
?Not[Left(A1,2)]Like"[#]#"And[A1]Like"[#][_a-zA-z0-9]*
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 79 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
f(a:r)=a=='#'&&r==""||r!!0>'@'&&all(\c->c=='_'||isAlphaNum c)r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Ba8IwFMfPzadII9gWrKiHHQaRqRvssHkRt8OU8mirCUuTkKRDod@9S42HHfYC7@U9fv9/XhjY71qIvueNVsbhZ3Aw3TAw6JTCo8koUJqMkvHYUEpI15k4ni2TJz8AIdJDmS9LDxRJ13G7EprBtm1wmZn@BwSvMMVfKCIjMhlyHUqxWm/CzTFuuQXZyvqi69LVlbgKJc/WGS7PFxVOYPe7F@ERruRiNn8gR8Tl3yde/SfUBH8qI6o4KOYLx9YVXEMnlctvgtCCsGqr3McwufOxRwooGFjm7VEDXHrzSqGoAf2OU@2XcniKTxm@GaFIt27nzJsk@RDkH/C@ZP8L)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>57</s> <s>54</s> 28 bytes

```
s->s.matches("#(?!\\d)\\w*")
```

Port of [Martin Ender's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85621/52210) to save a few bytes and match added test cases.
Not that [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) always matches the entire String, so no need for `^...$`.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY4xT8NADIX3/go3XRJEI9qBpQJEERILXSrEQBBy70xz5eKLck5phPLbw9FkRZHtwfL3nt8Bjzh3JfFBf3XKovfwjIZ/JgCGhapPVASbvxVg55wlZFDxVirDe/DJKhzaMKG9oBgFG2C4gc7Pb31aoKicfBzN4rtplukky74voqRb9Yqy3tmgGIRHZzQU4ffg/vYOmPSPt40XKlJXS1qGk1iOOVVx9ETWukt4dZXV0yg5p/mfnr1sHy0pMY6XV4vrcV5y441HrplOZRCSto11vPfnfCfX17jPYin5WmMzTo4TNI583K8fBqqdtN0v)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 92 bytes

```
s=>s[0]=='#'&s.Length>1&&(s[1]<48|s[1]>57)&s.Skip(1).All(x=>char.IsLetterOrDigit(x)|x=='_');
```

C# lambda (`Predicate`) where input is a `string` and output is a `bool`.

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3DxbYm)

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 39 bytes

```
print(arg[1]:match("^#[%a_][%a_%d]*$"))
```

Straightforward copypasta of match description. Outputs falsy `nil` if not hashtag, outputs truthly hashtag back otherwise.

Can be shortened for one more byte by using `find` if outputing list of two values (which is truthly) doesn't break rules.

Comment: I think this won't match a `#` on its own.

Comment: @MartinEnder, of course. It shouldn't. None of the top answers do that either. Also http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85619/hashtag-or-not/85797#comment210296_85619

Comment: Whether `#` is a hashtag on Twitter or Facebook is irrelevant to this challenge. The specification is very clear on the fact that `#` should be considered a hashtag for the purposes of this challenge. And while I haven't checked all of the answers, all I did check *do* accept `#` as a hashtag, so I'm not sure which top answers you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, <s>130</s> <s>135</s> 132 bytes

- +5 bytes to deal with an NPE that happened when the string consisted of only a hashtag.
- -2 bytes by using `Character/isLetterOrDigit`.

```clj
(fn[s](let[[h & r]s n(map int r)](and(= h\#)(not(<= 48(or(first n)0)57))(every? #(or(Character/isLetterOrDigit^long %)(= 95 %))n))))
```

Ungolfed:

```clj
(defn hashtag? [s]
  (let [[h & r] s
        codes (map int r)]
    (and (= h \#)
         (not (<= 48 (or (first codes) 0) 57))
         (every?
           #(or (Character/isLetterOrDigit ^long %)
                (= 95 %))
           codes))))
```

Comment: Whoops, this actually gives a NPE for "#". Give me a sec.